# Fibonacci function or sequence

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, fibonacci

The [Fibonacci sequence](http://oeis.org/A000045) is a sequence of numbers, where every number in the sequence is the sum of the two numbers preceding it.  The first two numbers in the sequence are both 1. Here are the first few terms:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 ...
```

---

Write the shortest code that either:

- Generates the Fibonacci sequence without end.
- Given `n` calculates the `n`th term of the sequence. (Either 1 or zero indexed)

You may use standard forms of input and output.

(I gave both options in case one is easier to do in your chosen language than the other.)

---

For the function that takes an `n`, a reasonably large return value (the largest Fibonacci number that fits your computer's normal word size, at a minimum) has to be supported.

---

#### Leaderboard

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 85; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 3; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    else console.log(body);
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() > b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() < b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: left !important;
  display: block !important;
}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/all.css?v=ffb5d0584c5f">
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am sort of waiting for a response like "f", 1 byte, in my math based golf language.

Comment: @ChrisJesterYoung can we use `1.0` are `1` only?

Comment: @NumberBasher 1.0 is fine.

Comment: What about 1.3?

Comment: Am I allowed to start the sequence with `0, 1`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

## Perl 6, 10 chars:

Anonymous infinite fibonacci sequence list:

```
^2,*+*...*
```

Same as:

```
0, 1, -> $x, $y { $x + $y } ... Inf;
```

So, you can assign it to an array:

```
my @short-fibs = ^2, * + * ... *;
```

or

```
my @fibs = 0, 1, -> $x, $y { $x + $y } ... Inf;
```

And get the first eleven values (from 0 to 10) with:

```
say @short-fibs[^11];
```

or with:

```
say @fibs[^11];
```

Wait, you can get too the first 50 numbers from anonymous list itself:

```
say (^2,*+*...*)[^50]
```

That returns:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765
10946 17711 28657 46368 75025 121393 196418 317811 514229 832040
1346269 2178309 3524578 5702887 9227465 14930352 24157817 39088169
63245986 102334155 165580141 267914296 433494437 701408733 1134903170 
1836311903 2971215073 4807526976 7778742049
```

And some simple benchmark:

```
real    0m0.966s
user    0m0.842s
sys     0m0.080s
```

With:

```
$ time perl6 -e 'say (^2, *+* ... *)[^50]'
```

EOF

Comment: I wouldn't even think of `^2` as replacement for `0,1`. +1

Comment: This is no longer valid, you will have to write it as `|^2,*+*...*`, which is the same number of bytes as `0,1,*+*...*`.

Comment: Perl is so weird.

Comment: What version of Perl 6 was this answer written in?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline There was a big change known as GLR (Great List Refactor) which happened shortly before the first official release which was on 2015-12-25. This code would have worked right up until that time.

Comment: `time perl6 -e 'say (|^2, *+* ... *)[^50]'` now reports 0.224s user time with the current version.

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills maybe Marco should change the title to "Perl 6 release candidate 1.2.3", but if a spec and interpreter were ever published for it then it's a valid language for PPCG.

Answer (score 92):

### Brainfuck, 22 bytes

```
+>++[-<<[->+>+<<]>>>+]
```

Generates the Fibonacci sequence gradually moving across the memory tape.

Comment: Beautiful! Litterally beautiful! Or perhaps not... anyways +1 for this :)

Comment: This is 3.344 or **4** bytes in compressed brainfuck. (6 ln(22)) / ln(256)

Comment: 16 bytes: `+[[<+>->+>+<<]>]`

Comment: @WillSherwood wouldn't it be `22*ln(6)/ln(256) = 7.1 => 8` instead?

Comment: 14 bytes: ```+[.[>+>+<<-]>]```

Comment: @Charlim I came up with a 14 byte solution back in 2014. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence/42443#42443

Comment: @primo Since you came up with a nice and short 16 bytes solution in 2016, I figured you'd be interested in my 14 bytes solution from the year 2014. (Which prints the characters instead of leaving them in the memory tape)

Comment: @Stefnotch of course, the shorter one is destructive. The solution above terminates with the fibonacci sequence on the tape, which is what the 16 byte solution also does.

Answer (score 55):

### Haskell, <s>17</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
f=1:scanl(+)1f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P83W0Ko4OTEvR0Nb0zDtf25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYJGSWJ2qoKhgYGCikKa5n8A)

Comment: Why not cut two spaces to `f=0:scanl(+)1 f`?

Comment: Wow, that's even shorter than the usual `f@(_:x)=0:1:zipWith(+)f x`! Have to remember it.

Comment: You may even strip another space: `f=0:scanl(+)1f`.

Answer (score 46):

### C# 4, 58 bytes

**Stream (69; 65 if weakly typed to `IEnumerable`)**

(Assuming a `using` directive for `System.Collections.Generic`.)

```
IEnumerable<int>F(){int c=0,n=1;for(;;){yield return c;n+=c;c=n-c;}}
```

**Single value (58)**

```
int F(uint n,int x=0,int y=1){return n<1?x:F(n-1,y,x+y);}
```

Comment: Given that `n` is a `uint`, `n==0` can be shortened to `n<1`. And the stream can save a few chars by ditching the space after the generic type and declaring `x` in a wider scope than necessary. In fact, ditch `x` entirely: `n+=c;c=n-c;`

Comment: @Peter: Thanks, will edit when I get some time.

Comment: Your single value version is as long as my recursive lambda expression answer...nice!

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44315/110 You can use C# 6 expression bodies to reduce some characters.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Can be golfed even more to `!n`, methinks.

Comment: @Ming-Tang `int F(uint n,int x=0,int y=1)=>n<1?x:F(n-1,y,x+y);` Although it does state C# 4...

Comment: @wizzwizz4 if I'm not mistaken, if `!n` works, then so should just `n` if you flip the conditional.

Comment: @Cyoce So, you're saying `int F(uint n,int x=0,int y=1){return n?F(n-1,y,x+y):x;}`?

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Not in C#. `n` is a `uint`, not a `bool`, and the type of the first operand of the conditional ?: operator has to be convertible to `bool`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Aw. And here I was thinking I'd beaten Jon Skeet at C#... :-)

Comment: @JonSkeet your first one is actually 68 bytes long, there's a trailing new line at the end.

Answer (score 34):

### GolfScript, 12

Now, just 12 characters!

```
1.{.@.p+.}do
```

Comment: +1 nice work. If you make it shorter than 13 chars, I'll instantly accept your answer (unless someone makes an even shorter answer, of course). :-P

Comment: I love a challenge. Done! ;-)

Comment: Nice, you win. At least, until someone makes something even shorter (if that's even possible). :-P

Comment: that definition is almost as short as the name 'Fibonacci' itself!  +1

Answer (score 26):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), <del>18</del> <del>14</del> 12

Thanks Martin for 6 bytes!

```
1="/}.!+/M8;
```

Expanded:

```
  1 = "
 / } . !
+ / M 8 ;
 . . . .
  . . .
```

[Try it online](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=MT0iL30uISsvTTg7&input=)

---

Old, answer. This is being left in because the images and explanation might be helpful to new Hexagony users.

```
!).={!/"*10;$.[+{]
```

Expanded:

```
  ! ) .
 = { ! /
" * 1 0 ;
 $ . [ +
  { ] .
```

This prints the Fibonacci sequence separated by newlines.

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=ISkuPXshLyIqMTA7JC5bK3td&input=) Be careful though, the online interpreter doesn't really like infinite output.

#### Explanation

There are two "subroutines" to this program, each is run by one of the two utilised IPs. The first routine prints newlines, and the second does the Fibonacci calculation and output.

The first subroutine starts on the first line and moves left to right the entire time. It first prints the value at the memory pointer (initialized to zero), and then increments the value at the memory pointer by `1`. After the no-op, the IP jumps to the third line which first switches to another memory cell, then prints a newline. Since a newline has a positive value (its value is 10), the code will always jump to the fifth line, next. The fifth line returns the memory pointer to our Fibonacci number and then switches to the other subroutine. When we get back from this subroutine, the IP will jump back to the third line, after executing a no-op.

The second subroutine begins at the top right corner and begins moving Southeast. After a no-op, we are bounced to travel West along the second line. This line prints the current Fibonacci number, before moving the memory pointer to the next location. Then the IP jumps to the fourth line, where it computes the next Fibonacci number using the previous two. It then gives control back to the first subroutine, but when it regains control of the program, it continues until it meets a jump, where it bounces over the mirror that was originally used to point it West, as it returns to the second line.

---

Preliminary Pretty Pictures!

The left side of the image is the program, the right hand side represents the memory. The blue box is the first IP, and both IPs are pointing at the next instruction to be executed.

[image]

Note: Pictures may only appear pretty to people who have similarly limited skill with image editing programs :P I will add at least 2 more iterations so that the use of the `*` operator becomes more clear.

Note 2: I only saw [alephalpha's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62716/31625) after writing most of this, I figured it was still valuable because of the separation, but the actual Fibonacci parts of our programs are very similar. In addition, this is the smallest Hexagony program that I have seen making use of more than one IP, so I thought it might be good to keep anyway :P

Comment: You should link to whatever you used to make the pretty pictures, then put the link on http://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexagony.

Comment: @mbomb007 I used gimp to manually create each frame, then uploaded  the images to some gif making website. Although, several times during this process I considered making a tool to do it, considering how tedious it was.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Impressive! Make it a challenge. I'm sure somebody will post an answer. :D Even better if you could create a website similar to fish's online interpreter.

Comment: @mbomb007 That might be a tad ambitious for a challenge on this site, not to mention it would probably suffer a lot from being really broad. I don't think I will post that, but feel free to do it yourself if you think you have a good way of presenting it. Also, I believe Timwi created a C# ide for hexagony, although I've never used it because I haven't bothered with mono.

Comment: @mbomb007 The ide lives [here](https://github.com/Timwi/EsotericIDE/), by the way, forgot to link it last time.

Comment: @mbomb007 and Fry: you can use ffmpeg to encode a video from a sequence of PNG images.  Supported video output formats include GIF and WEBM.  See [this Q&A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/creating-a-gif-animation-from-png-files): it's as simple as `ffmpeg -i %03d.png output.gif`

Answer (score 25):

## Python 2, 34 bytes

Python, using recursion... here comes a StackOverflow!

```
def f(i,j):print i;f(j,i+j)
f(1,1)
```

Answer (score 25):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) - 15 characters

```
0:nao1v
a+@:n:<o
```

Comment: Though you can shorten it to `0:nao1v LF a+@:n:<o` if you want to. Gives 15 :) In fact, this also makes the output slightly more readable...

Comment: 13 chars: `01r:nao$:@+$r`

Answer (score 25):

### J, 10 chars

Using built-in calculation of Taylor series coefficients so maybe little cheaty. Learned it [here](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Fibonacci%20Sequence#Generating_functions).

```
   (%-.-*:)t.

   (%-.-*:)t. 0 1 2 3 4 5 10 100
0 1 1 2 3 5 55 354224848179261915075
```

Comment: @aditsu `(q:^-^:p) 6` is `64 729` where p is even.
J is probably good for *what it does* riddles. :)

Comment: Even better: `(<:^-^:>) 4` is `81` and `<:^-^:> 4` is `53.5982`.

Comment: The emoji demonstrated here is what all J code should strive towards. On a side note, another alternative is `+/@:!&i.-` using 9 bytes.

Comment: @miles Very nice! You should post it as it is entirely different from mine.

Answer (score 21):

### [COW](http://esolangs.org/wiki/COW), 108

```
 MoO moO MoO mOo MOO OOM MMM moO moO
 MMM mOo mOo moO MMM mOo MMM moO moO
 MOO MOo mOo MoO moO moo mOo mOo moo
```

Answer (score 18):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
+¡1
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=K8KhMQ&input=MjA)

#### How it works

```
+¡1    Niladic link. No implicit input.
       Since the link doesn't start with a nilad, the argument 0 is used.

  1    Yield 1.
+      Add the left and right argument.
 ¡     For reasons‡, read a number n from STDIN.
       Repeatedly call the dyadic link +, updating the right argument with
       the value of the left one, and the left one with the return value.
```

<sup>‡</sup> `¡` peeks at the two links to the left. Since there is only one, it has to be the body of the loop. Therefore, a number is read from input. Since there are no command-line arguments, that number is read from STDIN.

Answer (score 15):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), 6 bytes

```
1.}=+!
```

Ungolfed:

```
  1 .
 } = +
  ! .
```

It prints the Fibonacci sequence without any separator.

Comment: This has the minor problem that it doesn't print any separator between the numbers. This isn't entirely well specified in the challenge though. (And I'm really happy someone is using Hexagony. :))

Answer (score 13):

## Ruby, <strike>29 27 25</strike> 24 bytes

```
p a=b=1;loop{b=a+a=p(b)}
```

Edit: made it an infinite loop. ;)

Comment: did anyone notice `b=a+a=b` is a palindrome? :)

Comment: yes st0le did :)

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but can someone explain how the `b=a+a=b` part works?  Can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @GigaWatt, Think of it this way, Instructions are executed left to right...so `newb=olda+(a=oldb)`

Comment: you can save 2 chars by using `loop`: `p 1,a=b=1;loop{p b=a+a=b}`

Comment: A little late to the party, but you can shave off another byte: `p a=b=1;loop{b=a+a=p(b)}`

Comment: On second thought: [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P9E2ydbQOic/v6A6ybZAI1FTGyhS@/8/AA)

Comment: @GB There is no `0` at the start though

Comment: @DialFrost, wasn't a requirement in the question.

Answer (score 12):

## Golfscript - single number - 12/11/10

12 chars for taking input from stdin:

```
~0 1@{.@+}*;
```

11 chars for input already on the stack:

```
0 1@{.@+}*;
```

10 chars for further defining 1 as the 0th Fibonacci number:

```
1.@{.@+}*;
```

Comment: The option is "Calculates, given n, the nth Fibonacci number". So ditch the `~` and you have 11 chars which take `n` on the stack and leave `F_n` on the stack.

Answer (score 12):

## [Prelude](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude), 12 bytes

One of the few challenges where Prelude is actually fairly competitive:

```
1(v!v)
  ^+^
```

This requires [the Python interpreter](https://web.archive.org/web/20060504072747/http://z3.ca/~lament/prelude.py) which prints values as decimal numbers instead of characters.

### Explanation

In Prelude, all lines are executed in parallel, with the instruction pointer traversing columns of the program. Each line has its own stack which is initialised to zero.

```
1(v!v)
  ^+^
| Push a 1 onto the first stack.
 | Start a loop from here to the closing ).
  | Copy the top value from the first stack to the second and vice-versa.
   | Print the value on the first stack, add the top two numbers on the second stack.
    | Copy the top value from the first stack to the second and vice-versa.
```

The loop repeats forever, because the first stack will never have a `0` on top.

Note that this starts the Fibonacci sequence from `0`.

Answer (score 11):

### DC (20 bytes)

As a bonus, it's even obfuscated ;)

```
zzr[dsb+lbrplax]dsax
```

EDIT: I may point out that it prints *all* the numbers in the fibonacci sequence, if you wait long enough.

Comment: I wouldn't call it obfuscated -- obfuscated code is supposed to be difficult to understand, and as far as dc goes the code here is completely straightforward.

Comment: I think dc(1) is inherently obfuscated.

Answer (score 11):

**Mathematica, 9 chars**

```
Fibonacci
```

If built-in functions are not allowed, here's an explicit solution:

**Mathematica, <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 31 chars**

```
#&@@Nest[{+##,#}&@@#&,{0,1},#]&
```

Comment: `#&@@Nest[{#+#2,#}&@@#&,{0,1},#]&` 32 chars.

Comment: @chyanog 31: `#&@@Nest[{+##,#}&@@#&,{0,1},#]&`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard 24 chars (26 bytes): `Round[GoldenRatio^#/√5]&`

Comment: or 23 chars (27 bytes): `Round[((1+√5)/2)^#/√5]&`

Answer (score 10):

## TI-BASIC, 11

By legendary TI-BASIC golfer Kenneth Hammond ("Weregoose"), from [this site](http://adriweb.free.fr/upload/ti/weregoose.html). Runs in O(1) time, and considers 0 to be the 0th term of the Fibonacci sequence.

```
int(round(√(.8)cosh(Anssinh‾¹(.5
```

To use:

```
2:int(round(√(.8)cosh(Anssinh‾¹(.5
                                     1

12:int(round(√(.8)cosh(Anssinh‾¹(.5
                                     144
```

How does this work? If you do the math, it turns out that `sinh‾¹(.5)` is equal to `ln φ`, so it's a modified version of Binet's formula that rounds down instead of using the `(1/φ)^n` correction term. The `round(` (round to 9 decimal places) is needed to prevent rounding errors.

Answer (score 9):

### K - 12

Calculates the `n` and `n-1` Fibonacci number.

```
{x(|+\)/0 1}
```

Just the `nth` Fibonacci number.

```
{*x(|+\)/0 1}
```

Comment: +1 Not bad! If you could shrink it just one character (and provide me a way to test it), I'll accept your answer. :-)

Comment: The only way to shrink it would be to replace the function with a call to a known number:

    n(|+\\)/0 1

Test it using [this interpreter](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona).

Comment: Could trim a byte by using `!2` in place of `0 1`: [`{x(|+\)/!2}`](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6qu0KjRjtHUVzSq5eJKUzfUVjQ0UNBXyCvJUEjMS1HI0zUEskpSi3KLubjSraq1EMoVuNLhyvPzcirBeqAqASbEGDo=)

Answer (score 9):

## Julia, 18 bytes

```
n->([1 1;1 0]^n)[]
```

Answer (score 8):

### Java, 55

I can't compete with the conciseness of most languages here, but I can offer a substantially different and possibly much faster (constant time) way to calculate the n-th number:

```
Math.floor(Math.pow((Math.sqrt(5)+1)/2,n)/Math.sqrt(5))
```

`n` is the input (int or long), starting with n=1. It uses [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) and rounds instead of the subtraction.

Comment: I love this solution

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, but it's early and I may be missing something! Assuming `0` to be the first number in the sequence, this gives `0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 8, 12, 21, 33` for the first 10 numbers

Comment: @Shaggy Oops! Sorry, I introduced a bug - fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

## [Dodos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/dodos), 26 bytes

```
	dot F
F
	F dip
	F dip dip
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8lPyS/@/58zJb9EwY3LjYvTTSElswBKgfD///8NDQA)

#### How it works

The function **F** does all the heavy lifting; it is defined recursively as follows.

```
F(n) = ( F(|n - 1|), F(||n - 1| - 1|) )
```

Whenever **n > 1**, we have **|n - 1| = n - 1 < n** and **||n - 1| - 1| = |n - 1 - 1| = n - 2 < n**, so the function returns **( F(n - 1), F(n - 2) )**.

If **n = 0**, then **|n - 1| = 1 > 0**; if **n = 1**, then **||n - 1| - 1| = |0 - 1| = 1 = 1**. In both cases, the attempted recursive calls **F(1)** raise a *Surrender* exception, so **F(0)** returns **0** and **F(1)** returns **1**.

For example, **F(3) = ( F(1), F(2) ) = ( 1, F(0), F(1) ) = ( 1, 0, 1 )**.

Finally, the **main** function is defined as

```
main(n) = sum(F(n))
```

so it adds up all coordinates of the vector returned by **F**.

For example, **main(3) = sum(F(3)) = sum(1, 0, 1) = 2**.

Comment: I read your README (DODOS) and am super intrigued; it’s a really neat concept! But I can’t find it on Esolangs or anywhere else. Did you come up with it?

Answer (score 8):

## [TypeScript's type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org), <strike>193</strike> <strike>188</strike> 186 bytes

```typescript
type L='length'
type T<N,U extends 0[]=[]>=U[L]extends N?U:T<N,[...U,0]>
type S<A,B>=T<A>extends[...infer U,...T<B>]?U[L]:0
type F<N>=N extends 0|1?N:[...T<F<S<N,1>>>,...T<F<S<N,2>>>][L]
```

There's no way to do I/O here, but we can use hovering to view the value (also note that the generated JS is empty):

[image: Fibonacci(10)]

Unfortunately, TypeScript has strict recursion limits and on F<sub>18</sub> we get a `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.` error:

[image: Fibonacci(11)]

[**Demo on TypeScript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAMgvAcgDYQHYHNgAsEChSRQAqAPAHIA0AqlBAB7BoAmAzlAAwDaAunDwHxwqnGN3qNUrKGQD8VAFylKnAHRqqFdt375w0AMokAghQBCg0kf7jmLVWoCWqAGYQATlA1qVpc9zki3PLsuoQAYuSCZLQMthwAPgCMMmTy9j4kEYaUifx5FN6kWeQUAEx5-NyBuDUowFDOiQDs8lARzfwA3Lh1DYkAHK3t-V1AA)

---

Ungolfed version:

```typescript
type NTuple<N extends number, Tup extends unknown[] = []> =
  Tup['length'] extends N ? Tup : NTuple<N, [...Tup, unknown]>;

type Add<A extends number, B extends number> =
  [...NTuple<A>, ...NTuple<B>]['length'];

type Sub<A extends number, B extends number> =
  NTuple<A> extends [...(infer Tup), ...NTuple<B>] ? Tup['length'] : never;

type Fibonacci<N extends number> =
  N extends 0 | 1 ? N : Add<Fibonacci<Sub<N, 1>>, Fibonacci<Sub<N, 2>>>;
```

Comment: In case you’re interested, here’s another approach, for 97 bytes: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268756/108687

Answer (score 7):

### 05AB1E, 7 bytes

Code:

```
1$<FDr+
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MSQ8RkRyKw)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Answer (score 7):

## [Whispers v3](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 35 bytes

```
> Input
> fₙ
>> 2ᶠ1
>> Output 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hMtOIe1R00wuOzsFo4fbFhiCGP6lJUAZBeP//wE) (or don't, as this uses features exclusive to v3)

Simply takes the first \$n\$ elements of the infinite list of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Code Gol...hey wait a minute

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>36</s> <s>35</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to dingledooper*

```
1x<>~~/^(..?)*$(??{++$i})/;say$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9n5evUJ5YlJeZl16soJ5aUZBalJmbmleSmGNlVZybWFSSm1iSnKFu/d@wwsaurk4/TkNPz15TS0XD3r5aW1sls1ZT37o4sVIl8/9/I9N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

This works by using the regex `^(..?)*$` to count [how many distinct partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Symbolic_method) \$n\$ has as a sum of the numbers \$1\$ and \$2\$.

For example, \$5\$ can be represented in the following \$8\$ ways:

```
1+1+1+1+1
1+1+1+2
1+1+2+1
1+2+1+1
1+2+2
2+1+1+1
2+1+2
2+2+1
```

This tells us that the \$F_5=8\$.

I had this basic idea on [2014-03-05](https://gist.github.com/Davidebyzero/9090628#gistcomment-1185486) but it didn't occur to me until today to try coding it into a program.

*The following two paragraphs explain the **33 byte** version:*

To count the number of distinct matches `^(..?)*$` can make in a string \$n\$ characters long, we must force Perl's regex engine to backtrack after every time the regex completes a successful match. Expressions like `^(..?)*$.` fail to do what we want, because Perl optimizes away the non-match, not attempting to evaluate the regex even once. But it so happens that it does *not* optimize away an attempt to match a backreference. So we make it try to match `\1`. This will always fail, but the regex engine isn't "smart" enough to know this, so it tries each time. (It's actually possible for a backreference to match after `$` with the multiline flag disabled, if it captured a zero-length substring. But in this particular regex, that can never happen.)

Embedded code is used to count the number of times the regex engine completes a match. This is the `(?{++$i})`, which increments the variable `$i`. We then turn it into a non-match after the code block executes.

To get this down to **32 bytes**, a "postponed" regular subexpression embedded code block is used, `$(??{`...`})` instead of `$(?{`...`})`. This not only executes the code, but then compiles that code's return value as a regex subexpression to be matched. Since the return value of `++$i` is the new value of `$i`, this will cause the match to fail and backtrack, since a decimal number (or any non-empty string) will never match at the end of a string.

This does make the 32 byte version about 7 times slower than the 33 byte version, because it has to recompile a different decimal number as a regex after each failed match (i.e. the same number of times as the Fibonacci number that the program will output). Using `(??{++$i,0})` is almost as fast as `(?{++$i})\1`, as Perl optimizes the case in which the return value has not changed last time. But that would defeat the purpose of using `$(??{`...`})` in the first place, because it would be 1 byte longer instead of 1 byte shorter.

As to the sequence itself – for golf reasons, the program presented above defines \$F_0=1,\ F_1=1\$. To define \$F_0=0,\ F_1=1\$ we would need an extra byte:

```
1x<>~~/^.(..?)*$(??{++$i})/;say$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9n5evUJ5YlJeZl16soJ5aUZBalJmbmleSmGNlVZybWFSSm1iSnKFu/d@wwsaurk4/Tk9DT89eU0tFw96@WltbJbNWU9@6OLFSJfP/fyOzf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

In the versions below, `(?{++$i})\1` is used for speed (at the golf cost of 1 extra byte), to make running the test suite more convenient.

Here it is as a (reasonably) well-behaved anonymous function (**<s>47</s> <s>46</s> 44 bytes**):

```
sub{my$i;1x pop~~/^.(..?)*$(?{--$i})\1/;-$i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5NCsIwFISv8pBAErXRIm6M1YuIEDXVB00aktS/UpcewCN6kdq6EFzNN/ANjNO@mLdV0BCix32U0PNFeYv2GCTY8leA6qvTHo22URWLRTDKR6Pi/kTH9FzioYuqMzGiKvCuD1SCuQHJszZUu9rcCMr0Cq50j8dkK5gQaz4kbF0nCcGGb9KJ7KGVfw/y0rN@mk0lwWU2S7sYjXgNmDOCvHYebRxs7KCBLwJBQeH9fAEVjOTJqre4bNoP) - Displays \$F_0\$ through \$F_{31}\$

The above actually runs faster than the standard recursive approach (**39 bytes**):

```
sub f{my$n=pop;$n<2?$n:f($n-2)+f($n-1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCsIwEEDRqwwl0IRgsRU3ToMXcaPSyIBOQ5IiErL1AB7Ri8Sa1f@L5yZ/35clTBCip2tE@P/z7Jn4FrCE5QI2PV6CjZsdCh6Ho@CDlYI3g9K1vcoF7ezlyshsUdBodv0arVUCWg2p5DxxbE7cZKgLgroWvu8PtJ2sRGEuPw) - Displays \$F_0\$ through \$F_{31}\$

If that is golfed down using [Xcali's technique](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182864/17216) it becomes even slower, at **38 bytes**:

```
sub f{"@_"<2?"@_":f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBcUpSZXGKtAGKXJxblZealF1v/Ly5NUkirVnKIV7IxsgdRVmkaIErXSFMbyjLUrP1vnZZfpJFbqZJpa2Ctkmlja2wIpLS1NasVMtM0VDI1qwuKMvNKlGLylGoVwEwFlUw9dYVHbZMU1PU0wEo0FWr/AwA) - Displays \$F_0\$ through \$F_{31}\$

or with the same indexing as my main answer here, **34 bytes**:

```
sub f{"@_"<2||f("@_"-2)+f("@_"-1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBcUpSZXGKtAGKXJxblZealF1v/Ly5NUkirVnKIV7IxqqlJ0wCxdI00taEsQ83a/9Zp@UUauZUqmbYG1iqZNrbGIEpbW7NaITNNQyVTs7qgKDOvRCkmT6lWAcxUUMnUU1d41DZJQV1PA6xEU6H2PwA) - Displays terms \$0\$ through \$30\$

See [Patience, young "Padovan"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182797/patience-young-padovan/223250#223250) for more variations and comparisons.

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 28 bytes

```
1x$_~~/^(..?)*$(??{++$\})/}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9n5evUJ5YlJeZl16soJ5aUZBalJmbmleSmGNlVZybWFSSm1iSnKFu/d@wQiW@rk4/TkNPz15TS0XD3r5aW1slplZTv7b6/38j03/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

I've just learned now, 16 months after posting the main answer above, that [Ton Hospel's Sum of combinations with repetition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155938/sum-of-combinations-with-repetition/155955#155955) answer used this same basic technique, predating my post by 3 years.

By combining the tricks used in that answer with those already used here, the program length can be reduced even further.

Perl actually literally wraps the program in a loop using string concatenation when called with `-p`, which I was surprised to learn (I would have implemented it in Perl as an emulated loop). So when this program is wrapped in `while (<>) {` ... `; print $_}` by the `-p` flag, it becomes:

```
while (<>) {1x$_~~/^(..?)*$(??{++$\})/}{; print $_}
```

`while (<>)` implicitly assigns the input from stdin, `<>`, to `$_` (which isn't done when using `<>` normally) at the beginning of each iteration of its loop.

`$\` is the `print` output terminator. By default it is empty, but the above program turns it into an integer by incrementing it on every possible match found by the regex. If only one number \$n\$ is sent to the program via stdin, followed by EOF, then upon exiting the loop `$\` will actually represent the \$n\$th Fibonacci number.

The `while (<>)` exits when it encounters EOF, giving `$_` an empty value. So then `print $_` will print that empty value, followed by the value of `$\`.

As such, it defeats the intended purpose of the `-p` flag, as this program works properly when given a single value followed by EOF; if given multiple newline delimited values, it will output the sum of those Fibonacci numbers after finally being sent EOF (if running the program interactively, this would be done by pressing Ctrl+D at the beginning of a line).

Contrast this with an actually loopable Perl `-p` program at **37 bytes**:

```
1x$_~~/^(..?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;$i%=$_=$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvNCoJAFAbQ/fcULibUJPVe/xXxTZIhhhrQUVRIiHz0JrcHzqyWIbNmct5yMdo8V8dV@6wWPSqzyaGu11Eu2yi3x8ttLO2iP47o7oVh51@F13WfIBD660eN0JdW9K3Q1sYgMBKkyJCjQIkKdCKBGJSAUlAGykEFqARV4Bh8HgYn4BSc/aZ505NZ7W0e/g)

If the same multiline input is given to the 28 byte program, this happens: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctLCoMwFAXQ@V2FA0GtVH1P468DN1JaQpFW0BhioILo0ps6PXB0b0bh1Ox9pVGDei9e0K@6N8PUKyvHtl0maewk7esT3Byt/vM40keYJF108cOu2@LYv@9Rum/OZSAwchQQKFGhRgM6kUAMykEFSIBKUAWqQQ04A5@HwTm4AIvfrO0wq8Vd9fgH)

Sadly, the `$\` trick can't be used with `say`; it only applies to `print`. The `$,` variable applies to both `print` and `say`, but only comes into play if at least two items are printed, e.g. `say"",""`.

Comment: You can convert this to Perl 6 using the `ex` flag to match all possible combinations. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WjvXKrVCP05DT89eU0tFvzZfwVChQuu/NVdxYqWCHlBNWn6RQpyhwX8A "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing Awesome, thanks! I was thinking of looking into Raku, but now I definitely will.

Comment: @JoKing Have you considered defining a SBCS for Raku? It's a shame not to be able to use `∘` as it would save a byte. There are probably plenty of other examples.

Comment: 33 with smartmatch: `1x<>~~/^(..?)*$(?{++$i})\1/;say$i`

Answer (score 7):

## [Trianguish](https://github.com/Radvylf/trianguish), <s>152</s> 135 bytes

```
00000000: 0c05 10d8 0201 40d7 0401 4110 4102 a060
00000010: 2c02 b080 2c02 8050 20e4 0211 0710 e209
00000020: 1110 4028 0d00 6020 2902 10c3 0802 a107
00000030: 02a1 0502 8027 0910 290b 1110 403b 0890
00000040: 204d 03d0 503c 0790 602a 1071 02a0 9027
00000050: 0280 b110 8111 0402 70e2 0501 402a 0202
00000060: 9106 1107 0291 0b11 0902 702b 1040 2a10
00000070: 6110 2102 9050 2802 70b1 1071 1104 1102
00000080: 02a1 0502 802c 05
```

[image: Two loop? Too many loop!]

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/trianguish/#bRpe5WBWEKfq54fcmvocykcKIEW_rK16GoV0e6r4lucnIdyGjbqJf3c9repFoZbw_neIAf.TpzYLM_49nZVTcuaHAboCGhtT0aTOf5j23UhN0GP.S0Qh2nYlxQT2rGokPwlJ_bsoF6-iPeFkRxL%7EJvlaoxY%7E-Cu47GiimG5Ib0E.HGAeRg69H)

---

Trianguish is my newest language, a cellular automaton sort of thing which uses a triangular grid of "ops" (short for "operators"). It features self-modification, a default max int size of 216, and an interpreter which, in my opinion, is the coolest thing I've ever created (taking over forty hours and 2k SLOC so far).

This program consists of two precisely timed loops, each taking exactly <s>17</s> 11 ticks. The first, in the top right is what actually does the fibonacci part; two S-builders are placed in exactly the right position such that two things occur in exactly the same number of ticks:

1. The left S-builder, `x`, copies its contents to `y`
2. The sum of `x` and `y` is copied to `x`

Precise timing is required, as if either of these occurred with an offset from the other, non-fibonacci numbers would appear in brief pulses, just long enough to desync everything. Another way this could have been done is with T-switches allowing only a single tick pulse from one of the S-builders, which would make precise timing unneeded, but this is more elegant and likely smaller.

The second loop, which is also 11 ticks, is pretty simple. It starts off with a 1-tick pulse of `1n`, and otherwise is `0n`, allowing an n-switch and t-switch to allow the contents of `x` to be outputted once per cycle. Two S-switches are required to make the clock use an odd number of ticks, but otherwise it's just a loop of the correct number of wires.

This program prints infinitely many fibonacci numbers, though if run with Mod 216 on, it will print them, as you might guess, modulo'd by 216 (so don't do that :p).

Comment: yo dang that's a cool lang

Answer (score 7):

## K - 8 bytes

```
+/[;1;0]
```

### Explanation

It makes use of ngn/k's recurrence builtin.

### How to use

Calculates the `n`th fibonacci number.

To calculate the `n`th put the number at the end of the program:

```
+/[;1;0]40
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: It's annoying how this doesn't seem to be documented. (and hence I have no idea how it works, lol)

Comment: Yeah its not really documented because its specific to ngn/k, but here is something:
https://ngn.codeberg.page/txt/slash.html
So it just applies `F` to the previous two items. And if you use the 4 arg overload, it applies `F` to every 3 previous elements and so on. hopefully that clears some things up :)

Comment: Ah I see, so the `[...;...;]` is just a way of providing multiple arguments to `+/`? The main problem is that the ngn/k documentation isn't very verbose, it just says like one word to say what a function does, so it doesn't make sense often.

Answer (score 6):

### Ruby, 25 chars

st0le's answer shortened.

```
p 1,a=b=1;loop{p b=a+a=b}
```

Comment: Actually you can shorten it even further using `a=b=1;loop{p a;b=a+a=b}`

Comment: So you st0le his answer? :P

Answer (score 6):

#### FAC: Functional APL, 4 characters (!!)

Not mine, therefore posted as community wiki.  FAC is a dialect of APL that Hai-Chen Tu apparently suggested as his PhD dissertation in 1985. He later wrote an article together with Alan J. Perlis called "[FAC: A Functional APL Language](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1308785)".  This dialect of APL uses "lazy arrays" and allow for arrays of infinite length.  It defines an operator "iter" (`⌼`) to allow for compact definition of some recursive sequences.

The monadic ("unary") case of `⌼` is basically Haskell's `iterate`, and is defined as `(F⌼) A ≡ A, (F A), (F (F A)), …`.  The dyadic ("binary") case is defined somewhat analogously for two variables: `A (F⌼) B ≡ A, B, (A F B), (B F (A F B)), …`.  Why is this useful? Well, as it turns out this is precisely the kind of recurrence the Fibonacci sequence has.  In fact, one of the examples given of it is

```
1+⌼1
```

producing the familiar sequence `1 1 2 3 5 8 …`.

So, there you go, quite possibly the shortest possible Fibonacci implementation in a non-novelty programming language. :D

Comment: Oh, I accidentally un-community-wikied your post as part of my (manual) bulk-unwikiing. Oh well. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

### Brainfuck, <strike>16,15,</strike> 14/13 chars

```
+[[->+>+<<]>]
```

Generates the Fibonacci sequence and does not print out anything.
Also, is shorter than the one above.

```
+[.[->+>+<<]>]
```

This one has 14 characters but prints out ASCII characters with the the values of the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: This is good, but would I be incorrect in saying that the 14 byte version only outputs from the 2nd 1 on?  As in "1 2 3 5 8" instead of "1 1 2 3 5 8"?

Comment: @Charlim Oh, you're right. I have no idea what the me of 2014 thought. Anyways, I just fixed it by moving the print instruction to the front of the loop.

Answer (score 6):

## [Desmos](http://www.desmos.com/calculator), 61 bytes

### [Golfed](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ursfqoypnp)

Click the `add slider` button for `n`.

```
p=.5+.5\sqrt{5}
n=0
f=5^{-.5}\left(p^n-\left(-p\right)^{-n}\right)
```

The last line is the output.

### Ungolfed

Is a function.

```
\phi =\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
f_{ibonacci}\left(n\right)=\frac{\phi ^n-\left(-\phi \right)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}
```

Answer (score 6):

## R, 40 bytes

Haven't seen a R solution, so:

```
f=function(n)ifelse(n<3,1,f(n-1)+f(n-2))
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but you can shorten to [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P802rTQvuSQzP08jTzMhMy1BI8/GWMdQJ00jT9dQUxtEGWlq/k/TMDLQ/A8A)

Answer (score 6):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 10 bytes

Non competing answer because the language is newer than the question.

Cubix is a new 2 dimensional language by @ETHproductions were the code is wrapped onto a cube sized to fit.

```
;.o.ON/+!)
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix)

This wraps onto a 2 x 2 cube in the following manner

```
    ; .
    o .
O N / + ! ) . .
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

- `O` output the value of the TOS
- `N` push newline onto stack
- `/` reflect north
- `o` output the character of the TOS
- `;` pop TOS
- `/` reflect east after going around the cube
- `+` add top 2 values of the stack
- `!` skip next command if TOS is 0
- `)` increment the TOS by 1.  This kicks off the sequence essentially.

This is an endless loop that prints the sequence with a newline separator.  It take advantage of the fact that most commands don't pop the values from the stack.
If the separator is ignored then this can be done with 5 bytes `.O+!)`

Answer (score 5):

### GolfScript, 13 chars

```
2,~{..p@+.}do
```

(My answer from a [previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232861/fibonacci-code-golf).)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, <s>41</s> <s>39</s> 33 bytes

```
(c=(a,b)=>alert(a)+c(b,a+b))(0,1)
```

Comment: I don't think the function without the parenthesis is still valid.

Comment: I don't believe this is valid because ES6 came after the challenge was created. Even if it was, you could save a byte by making it a function to return `fib(n)`: `f=(n,a=0,b=1)=>n?f(n-1,b,a+b):a;`

Answer (score 5):

## Common Lisp, 38 bytes

Generates the Fibonacci sequence without end.

```
(do((a 1 b)(b 1(+ a b)))(())(print a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jJV9DI1HBUCFJUyNJwVBDWyERyNTU1NAA4oKizLwShURNzf//AQ)

The [other Common Lisp solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1963/41789) is a function to generate the *n*-th number. This solution works since in the `do` loop the assignments to the iteration variables are performed in parallel: so the initialization is equivalent to:

```
a, b = 1, 1
```

while at each repetition the assignment is equivalent to:

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

Comment: Hi sorry is there a way to make it print a certain number of fibonacci numbers? Thanks

Comment: @DialFrost, yes, for instance with this function: `(defun f(x)(do((a 1 b)(b 1(+ a b))(i 0 (1+ i)))((= i x)a)))`. Note that the function is 0-indexed.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 bytes

This algorithm is based on Pascal's Triangle, and I take no credit for it. Simply submitting it for completeness.

```apl
+.!∘⌽⍨⍳
```

`+.!` is the summation of binomial coefficients. In this context k!n can be thought of as the kth element in the nth row of Pascal's Triangle (zero indexed).

`∘` is the function composition operator called Beside.

`⌽` reverses the array.

`⍨` is the commute operator, known as Selfie, it's used to copy the array to the left side of the composed function.

`⍳` the index generator creates a range, from 0–(n-1) inclusive.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OApLae4qOOGY969j7qXfGod/P//2kKBlxpCoZAbATExkBsAsSmQGwGxOZAbAHEliA1IIWmYNUGECaUDaZMzM0A)

Answer (score 5):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) `-n`, <s>30</s> 28 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)!

Prints the infinite sequence.

```
[0,1]|while(1;[last,add])[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z/aQMcwtqY8IzMnVcPQOjonsbhEJzElJVYz2jD2//9/@QUlmfl5xf918wA)

Start with `[0,1]`.
`while(1; ... )` infinite loop, `1` is a truthy value.
`[last,add]` the new pair is the last value of the old pair and the sum of the old pair.
`while` returns all intermediate pairs, `[1]` gets the second element of each pair.

---

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>35</s> 33 bytes

A recursive filter written for [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235138/64121).

```
def f:(.<2//[.-1,.-2|f]|add?)//.;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8lNU0hzUpDz8ZIXz9aT9dQR0/XqCYttiYxJcVeU19fz/p/UWJeeqqGoYFmTdr/f/kFJZn5ecX/dfOKAA)

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z/aQMcwtqY8IzMnVcPQOjonsbhEJzElJVYz2jD2//9/@QUlmfl5xf918wA)

Comment: For the record, another 28-byte solution: [1,1]|recurse([last,add])[0]

Answer (score 5):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 12 chars

```
|1 ⍥ (+,,) ↶ .1
```

[Try It Online!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=f%20%E2%86%90%20%7C1%20%E2%8D%A5%28%2B%2C%2C%29%E2%86%B6.1%0Af%2010)

#### Explanation:

```
.1 - repeat last item on stack: essentialy gives 1 1 

↶ unroll - takes your user input (an natural number) and makes it the argument to the repeat

(+,,) - the function to repeat. it take the last two items from the stack, sum them and push to the top

⍥ - repeat modifier, takes the function and number of repeats as arguments

|1 - tells the compiler how many args to take as input
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

#### Windows PowerShell – <s>34</s> 30

```
for($b=1){$a,$b=$b,($a+$b)
$a}
```

Comment: You can save 3 by doing away with defining $a at the start (assuming $a is not already defined in the environment), and moving the echo of $a to the end of the loop.

Comment: I can even save one more by including the initialisation in the loop header.

Comment: Wow. I never actually ran this until today for some reason. It's interesting that, past around 1E+308, PowerShell just gives up and calls it `Infinity`.

Comment: I put together a solution, somewhat based on this, that accepts user input and outputs the nth number. Came out to 45 characters. You want that here, or as a separate answer?

Comment: @Iszi, give a separate answer, I guess. It solves a different problem, after all.

Comment: Thanks. [Done.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15504/9387)

Comment: @Iszi That's because beyond 1e308 it's no longer representable in a double-precision float

Comment: @Iszi That's because beyond 1e308 it's no longer representable in a double-precision float

Answer (score 4):

## bc, 36 chars

```
r=0;l=1;while(i++<99){r+=l;l+=r;r;l}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Javascript, <s>27</s> <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 23 characters

```
for(a=b=1;n--;)a+=b=a-b
```

In an interactive javascript command line (Like google chrome console) it'll print out the nth fibonacci term for n > 1. undefined for n=1, runs forever for n < 1.

Credit to Bojidar Marinov

#### 41 characters

```
for(x=[1,1],y=1;n-++y;)x[y]=x[y-1]+x[y-2]
```

Saving the n (>=2) first terms in an array.

Comment: 25: `for(b=a=1;n--;)b*=a=1+1/a`
23: `for(a=b=1;n--;)a+=b=a-b`

Answer (score 4):

## C: <strike>48</strike> 47 characters

A really really truly ugly thing. It recursively calls main, and spits out warnings in any sane compiler. But since it compiles under both Clang and GCC, without any odd arguments, I call it a success.

```
b;main(a){printf("%u ",b+=a);if(b>0)main(b-a);}
```

<strike>It prints numbers from the Fibonacci sequence until the integers overflow, and then it continues spitting out ugly negative and positve numbers until it segfaults. Everything happens in well under a second.</strike>

Now it actually behaves quite well. It prints numbers from the Fibonacci sequence and stops when the integers overflow, but since it prints them as unsigned you never see the overflow:

```
VIC-20:~ Fors$ ./fib
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946 17711 28657 46368
75025 121393 196418 317811 514229 832040 1346269 2178309 3524578 5702887 9227465 14930352
24157817 39088169 63245986 102334155 165580141 267914296 433494437 701408733 1134903170
1836311903 2971215073 VIC-20:~ Fors$
```

Comment: Printing out overflowed numbers and/or segfaulting is probably not part of the spec, but nice try. :-)

Comment: Certainly, but it's not the only solution here that segfaults. :) I will edit it so that it behaves more properly, since I got the character count down anyway.

Comment: Yay! Have an upvote. :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could shave off 2 bytes by replacing `if(b>0)` with `b>0&&` and yes, I realize this post is over 4 years old :)

Answer (score 4):

## **C#: 38 (40 to ensure non-negative numbers)**

Inspired by the beauty of Jon Skeet's C# answer and St0le's answer, another C# solution in only 38 characters:

```
Func<int,int>f=n=>n>2?f(n-1)+f(n-2):1;
```

Tested with:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(f(i));
```

Yay for recursive `Func<>`! Incorrect when you pass in negative numbers, however - corrected by the 40 character version, which doesn't accept them:

```
Func<uint,uint>f=n=>n>2?f(n-1)+f(n-2):1;
```

**Note**: as pointed out by @Andrew Gray, this solution doesn't work in Visual Studio, as the compiler rejects the in-line function definition referring to itself. The Mono compiler at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php, however, runs it just fine. :)

[image: Mono Compilation]

**Visual Studio: 45**

```
Func<int,int>f=null;f=n=>n>2?f(n-1)+f(n-2):1;
```

Comment: looks rather familiar...dunno where I've seen that before... ;)

As far as I can tell, though, in C# this is the best way of doing it.  However, your way won't work - you have to assign null to your function to use a recursive lambda.  As that code stands, it won't compile, with a syntax error 'use of unassigned function f' at the line that your lambda is being defined at.

Comment: Depends on your compiler. :) It does exactly as you say in Visual Studio - but the Mono compiler at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php runs it perfectly as-is.

Comment: Didn't know that.  I wonder why VS and Mono went two different directions on this one...or, maybe the Mono guys are just smarter.  The answer is beyond me. D:

Comment: Updated to clearly point out our findings. ;)

Comment: Does this handle the `F(0)=0` case? It's an easy fix that doesn't cost any extra bytes: just exchange `:1` for `:n`

Answer (score 4):

**GNU Octave: 19 chars**

```
@(x)([1,1;1,0]^x)(1)
```

This solution has the distinction of running in O(log n) time.

Comment: Edited it to a language that I can test.

Answer (score 4):

## [Detour](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html) (non-competing), 8 bytes

```
[$<<]!S.
```

[Try it online!](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html?hex=WyQ8PF0hUy4%3D)

This one is shorter than the word "fibonacci"

```
[$<<]!S.
Fibonacci
```

explanation:

```
[   ]     # while n > 0
 $<<       # replace n with [n-1, n-2]
     !S.  # invert, output
```

Just for fun, here's one that will always take exactly 19 ticks to terminate, whether given 0 or 1474. On my really old macbook, it on average terminates after 7ms.

---

## [Detour](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html), <s>30</s> 28 bytes

```
$Q{G<!d}seQ
.{5Vg>d}se-$G_c!
```

[Try it online!](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html?hex=JFF7RzwhZH1zZVEKLns1Vmc+ZH1zZS0kR19jIQ%3D%3D)
This is the way of expressing `(((1+sqrt(5))/2)^n-((1-sqrt(5))/2)^n)/sqrt(5)`

Old way:

---

## [Detour](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html) (non-competing), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
<Q>S.
;$<
```

[Try it online!](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html?hex=PFE+Uy4KOyQ8)

This is non-competing: I just pushed the required version of the language about 10 minutes ago.

Detour works like befunge, fish etc. except for one crucial difference: where those languages redirect the instruction pointer, detour redirects data.

Input is pushed in at the beginning of the middle line (in this case the first). `<` decrements a number, `>` increments it. `Q` sends it down if a number is greater than 0, forward otherwise.

the line `;$<` is the same as `$<;` because edges wrap. What it does is take the number it is given, then push that number and 1 less than that number to the input. This is how detour does recursion.

`S` reduces with addition, and `.` outputs the result.

For a better explanation, visit the site and it will give a visual representation of all the numbers.

Answer (score 4):

## [Cy](https://github.com/cyoce/Cy), <s>33</s> <s>31</s> 30 bytes (non-competing)

This is going for the function option (takes N, outputs `F(N)`)

```rb
0 1 :>i {1 - $&+ times} &if :<
```

Ungolfed/explanation:

```rb
0 1       # first two fibs are 0, 1
:>i       # read input as integer (let's call it N)
{
  1 -    
    {&+}      # add the last two values
  times     # repeat N-1 times ^
} &if     # if N is non-zero ^
:<        # output the last calculated value (if N is 0, that would be 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 11 bytes

```
10r:n:@+aor
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39CgyCrPykE7Mb/o/38A)

Prints the Fibonacci sequence forever, separated by newlines.

Answer (score 4):

## [AsciiDots](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots), <s>22</s> <s>21</s> <s>20</s> <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
/.{+}-\
\#$*#1)
```

Prints the Fibonacci sequence. Outgolfs the [sample](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots/blob/master/samples/fibonacci.compact.dots) by <s>12</s> <s>13</s> <s>14</s> <s>17</s> <s>18</s> 19 bytes. This is now just <s>1 byte longer than</s> exactly as long as a [simple counter!](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots/blob/master/samples/counter.compact.dots) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxOzsxMyS8p/v9fX69au1Y3hitGWUVL2VDz/38A)

---

## [AsciiDots](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots), <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```
 /#$\
.>*[+]
/{+}*
^-#$)
\1#-.
```

Here's a faster version. It prints out the Fibonacci sequence at a rate of 1 number per 5 ticks, compared to the maximally golfed version's 1 per <s>8</s> <s>10</s> <s>8</s> <s>12</s> 14 ticks. It's twice as fast as the [sample](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots/blob/master/samples/fibonacci.compact.dots) and is still shorter by <s>3</s> 4 bytes! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxOzsxMyS8p/v9fQV9ZJYZLz04rWjuWS79au1aLK05XWUWTK8ZQWVfv/38A)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
Åf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGva//@GAA)

1-indexed. Built-in.

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
λ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3G7t//8B)

0-index. Non-built-in. As far as I know, this is the first answer using *the major* 05AB1E rewrite, and uses its newest addition, `λ...}`, recursive list generation.

#### How it works

```
λ+ – Full program.
λ  – Starting from 1, recursively apply a function and collect the results
     in an infinite list.
 + – Addition.
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), <s>104</s> 87 bytes

<sup>-10 bytes thanks to [ASCII-only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39244/ascii-only)!</sup>

```bash
_->b+c+m
m+b->m+a+d
m+0b->n
n+c->n+b+d
n+0c->Out_a+Out_" "+o
o+d->o+c
o+0d+a->o
o+0a->m
```

Produces infinitely many Fibonacci numbers, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjLCcAgEIThu1UEr4MgKcAWUoL4CETIugFN@9msl/k/Jt3lOqmNKRJdyCggQ8guEBKq0qu76SgaZL06vPp4Z0xYazcLNozqAqMofEVSL2lJ5ONnNu5DXN1/)

### Ungolfed

```bash
_ -> b + c + s0

# a,d <- b
s0 +  b -> s0 + a + d
s0 + 0b -> s1

# b,d <- c
s1 +  c -> s1 + b + d
s1 + 0c -> Out_a + Out_" " + s2

# c <- d & clear a
s2 +  d     -> s2 + c
s2 + 0d+  a -> s2
s2     + 0a -> s0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1RCsIwEET/c4qlgj8aSPMtXsEjlGS3YKFaceP1G3e6C0smbyaTsvJzfi3aep8o3qnShdhWUwgnKlehW6QaNBkz0xKHLLbiNDkdka@e56Aj8uyOyep5yHTQx69NKME50IAfMxoY74XOxOtcvlSCZjQJYdCGKztNYk5xCoIx6iT1vm@ftmxv7VHyHw)

Comment: [95?](https://tio.run/##FclBCsMwEAPAu5@RqzA4H/C9p36gYBxvoYHubiEu5PXdKhdphPp7vJ66HzOi5XqzdmLDgCbFlquiQ8hCWzIMFn8hTxSu@3e2jiuXhy3w5JBcHYMogk5fYmvEWn7@mbvbEVnWPw) too lazy to check if algo is shorter

Comment: [94 and left sides in better order](https://tio.run/##FclBCsMwDETRvU8Rsh0EzgW876pHMI5UaKCyCnEgp4@ibOY/mPbj70e3fbhXKq9eT6xgaFKsVBQNEszhnjo4Er8EM@Ok8j5GbXh2nmZYMggVAweyoIUfRdV9yZf9x2Z9d5LlBg)

Comment: @ASCII-only: Nice! Noticed I can also output \$\infty\$ many terms, saved another 7 bytes.. but Alchemist indeed needs some work done (atm. it only works when properly killing the process due to some buffering issues).

Comment: lol > bytes bytes

Answer (score 4):

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), <s>34</s> 31 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to H.PWiz!*

```
__('__=_/_;'+'_,_=_+__,__;_'*_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/Pl5DPT7eNl4/3lpdWz1eB8jUjgdS8dbx6lrxmv///zcBAA)

Returns the nth element of the Fibonacci, 1-indexed, starting from `1,1,2,3,5...`.

#### Explanation:

```
__(                           ) # Eval as Python code
   '__=_/_;'                    # Set __ to 1
            +'             '*_  # Then repeat input times
              _,_=_+__,__;      # On the first iteration, set _ to __ (1)
                         ;_     # On future iterations, prepend a _
             __,_=_+__,__;      # Set __ to the next fibonacci number
                                # And set _ to the old value of __
                                # Implicitly output _
```

Or, H.PWiz's version:

```
__('_=__=_/'+'_;__,_=_+__,_'*_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/Pl5DPd42Hoj01bXV463j43WAbG0Qpa4Vr/n//39DAwA)

#### Explanation:

```
__('_=__=_/'+'_;__,_=_+__,_'*_)

__(                           ) # Eval as Python code
   '_=__=_/'+'_;                # Set both _ and __ to 1
             '             '*_  # Repeat input times
                __,_=_+__,__    # Set __ to the next fibonacci number
                                # And set _ to the old value of __
                __,_=_+__,_     # Except on the last iteration
                                # Implicitly output _
```

Comment: This is possible in 31 bytes. See if you can see how :)

Answer (score 4):

## Intel 8087 FPU, 13 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: d9e8 d9ee dcc1 d9c9 e2fa df35 c3         ...........5.
```

**Listing:**

```
D9 E8       FLD1                ; push initial 1 into ST(1)
D9 EE       FLDZ                ; push initial 0 into ST
        FIB_LOOP:
DC C1       FADD ST(1), ST      ; ST(1) = ST(1) + ST 
D9 C9       FXCH                ; Exchange ST and ST(1)
E2 FA       LOOP FIB_LOOP       ; loop until n = 0
DF 35       FBSTP [DI]          ; store result as BCD to [DI]
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

As a callable function, input `n` in `CX`, output to a 10 byte little-endian packed BCD representation at `[DI]`. This will compute up to Fibonacci `n`=`87` using the Intel x87 math-coprocessor using 80-bit extended-precision floating point arithmetic.

Run using DOS DEBUG with `n` = `9`, result `34`:

[image]

`n` = `87` (`0x57`), result `679891637638612258`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), 385 bytes

```
   ^           ^
  / \         /l\
 /set\       /oop\
^-----^     ^-----^
-    ^-    /]\   ^-^
    ^-    ^---^ ^- -^
   ^-    ^-   -/ \  -^
  ^-     -^   /set\  -^
 /[\     / \ ^-----^  -^
^---^   /out\-    ^-  / \
-^  -^ ^-----^   /+\ /set\
/1\ / \-    /x\ ^---^-----^
---/set\    --- -  /x\   /+\
  ^-----^          ---  ^---^
 /x\   /1\             /x\  -
 ---   ---             ---
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/RCsIwDEXf8xX3XULY9xgLogMHjg43Qb@@tknbzTyU5PbkJlm@r@s83Xm9PcZ5TAlAwB6BAIH2Wp5KkHXcmiQxLkqBS3hjzYm9MOiilhe3pgVryLmrYcfZBprsKsy5Ti26nH18Afvo/BHqEhLfm3bDTJEDOww5qTuSDFoQX/Tjhv0G5n5szsGOWDsBx7PRGDegBg6KY5jK5GR9//pT@gE)

This guy's a whopper. Prints terms indefinitely with no separator. The bit on the left initializes the blank variable and `x` to one, and the bit on the right does the Fibonaccing. The loop condition (everything to the left below `loop`) prints both variables before checking the blank one for truthiness (it'll always be nonzero). The loop body updates first blank and then `x`, thus generating the next two terms for the condition to print.

I can't quite figure out `set`. It doesn't quite follow the chain of execution, but it *almost* does, I think. I'll be looking at the Pyramid Scheme source in the next few days (and possibly extending the language); perhaps this will provide me with the insight required to golf some bytes off this monstrosity.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
1⟦⟨t≡+⟩ⁱh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9icmFjaHlsb2cy/@KGsOKCgeG6ieKKpf8x4p@m4p@odOKJoSvin6nigbFo//8)

[Generates](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/85334) an infinite list of Fibonacci numbers through the output variable.

```
1⟦           Starting with [0, 1],
       ⁱ     iterate some (possibly zero) number of times:
  ⟨ ≡ ⟩      pair
   t         the last element with
     +       the sum of the two elements.
        h    Yield the first element of the result.
```

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
0;1⟨{tẉ₂}↰+⟩
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9icmFjaHlsb2cy//8wOzHin6h7dOG6ieKCgn3ihrAr4p@p//8)

Prints terms infinitely, separated by newlines.

```
0;1             Starting with [0,1],
    {tẉ₂}       get and print the second element,
          +     sum the two elements,
   ⟨     ↰ ⟩    and recur on the pair of those two values.
```

A variant to find the nth term of the sequence, 0-indexed:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
∧0;1⟨t≡+⟩ⁱ↖?t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AU4Asf9icmFjaHlsb2cy/3t3IiAtPiAidz/ihrDigoLhuol94bWQ/@KIpzA7MeKfqHTiiaEr4p@p4oGx4oaWP3T//1swLDEsMiwzLDQsNSwxMF0)

Comment: An interesting [(very slow)](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/qHPOo5apj9o2PGpqfLir81HX0v/VD3c0A3l1yTkPt0541NNpY1z7cNuc//8B) 12-byter, 0-indexed but wrong on element 0: `{ḃ₁~clᵐ⌉<3}ᶜ`

Answer (score 4):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 8 bytes

Generates the sequence.

```
v+"}
1"1
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiditcIn1cbjFcIjEiLCJ2IjoxLCJpIjoiIn0=)

[image]

The values (initially `1` and `1`) follow the conveyor belts indicated by the arrow heads. `"` duplicates the input into both outputs, `+` adds them, and `}` writes them to the output.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
ÞF
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%C3%9EF%2C&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Before you go saying that the online link doesn't match the submission here, that's because the extra `,` is needed to actually make the output appear online. If you use the offline version, then you will see that the above works just fine. Also, the `5` flag makes sure that the online interpreter times out after 5 seconds.

### Explained

```
ÞF  # Push every Fibonacci number
```

And now for the non-trivial version

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `5`, 6 bytes

```
⁽+dk≈Ḟ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%E2%81%BD%2Bdk%E2%89%88%E1%B8%9E&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Once again, discrepancies between online link and actual version are for the purposes of making it work online.

#### Explained

```
⁽+dk≈Ḟ
⁽+d     # lambda x, y: x + y
   k≈   # the list [0, 1]
     Ḟ  # Create an infinite sequence based on the function and the initial list.
```

Fun fact: the infinite sequence function you see was inspired by the sequence blocks of the golfing language Arn by ZippyMagician.

Comment: Fun fact: I was inspired by Raku when I added sequences

Answer (score 4):

## [COBOL (GNU)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/), 170 bytes

I am surprised at the lack of COBOL answers on this site. Well, it is ancient after all.

This outputs the fibonacci sequence correctly up to 38 digits.

```cobol
PROGRAM-ID.H.DATA DIVISION.LOCAL-STORAGE SECTION.
1 a PIC 9(38).
1 b PIC 9(38).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.G.COMPUTE a=0**b+b -a
ADD a TO b
DISPLAY b(38- FUNCTION LOG10(b):)GO G.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc2xDsIgFIXhvU9xR1sDaeOiJg4EEEloIUBNHKFpuzQ20fj6Yuui43@G73RznCc03l8pGauFJTWSDF8wI54Ak1fppG6w0pQo5Ly2RHBwnPp1zSoIYCSFw2a3z9eM/7l4lLPW8p8jMNW1aT2HcCqLIm4joJARxhbIa4gZk84ocoO4EAjObfN9AqVFVW5ifsyFBoFTenfDFMZnQsOj7z8)

### Explanation

We just need two variables, `a` and `b` to compute the whole fibonacci sequence. Here is pseudocode of what this would look like:

```py
a = 0
b = 1
loop {
  a = b - a
  b += a
  print(a)
}
```

Translating the pseudocode above in COBOL is relatively short and simple. But we see that variables in COBOL are set to `0` by default, and having one of them set to a `1` is kind of <sup>(8 bytes)</sup> long, so we hack it out like so:

```py
a = 0
b = 0
loop {
  a = b - a + 0 ** b
  b += a
  print(b)
}
```

The `0 ** b` ensures that `a = 1` on the first iteration. From then on, the logic is the same as in our first pseudocode implementation (since `0 ** (any number greater than 0) = 0`). The change from `print(a)` to `print(b)` is just to ensure that the numbers are outputted in the correct order.

#### Ungolfed

```cobol
PROGRAM-ID. H.

DATA DIVISION.
LOCAL-STORAGE SECTION.
1 a PIC 9(38).                     // Declare a variable named `a` (a = 0)
1 b PIC 9(38).                     // Declare a variable named `b` (b = 0)

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
G.                                 // Define a label named `G`
COMPUTE a=0**b+b -a                // a = b - a + 0 ** b
ADD a TO b                         // b += a
DISPLAY b(38- FUNCTION LOG10(b):)  // Print `b` without trailing zeros
GO G.                              // Jump to the label named `G` (4 lines above)
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried changing 38 to 6 in your code so it prints up to 832040 only, but it seems to continue printing afterwards, any clue why? thx

Comment: The program is an infinite loop, so you would have to exit the loop to stop it from printing.

Answer (score 4):

## [Quipu](https://github.com/cgccuser/quipu), 33 bytes

```
1&0&\n
[][]/\
^^/\0&
--++??
1&
++
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m720sDSzoHTBgqWlJWm6FjcVDdUM1GLyuKJjo2P1Y7ji4vRjDNS4dHW1te3tuQzVuLS1IQqh6mH6AA)

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king).

It prints the Fibonacci sequence separated by newlines.

Equivalent pseudocode:

```
  a = [0, 0, 0]    // implicitly
0:
  a[0] = a[1] - a[0] + 1
1:
  print a[0]
  a[1] = a[0] + a[1]
2:
  print "\n"
  goto 0
```

Comment: Kaogu. (15chrs)

Answer (score 4):

## [Halfwit](https://github.com/chunkybanana/halfwit/), 5.5 bytes

```
n><?(:}+
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoYWxmd2l0IixudWxsLCJuPjw/KDp9KyIsIiIsIls2XSIsIiJd)

Halfwit's an experimental golfing language where most commands fit within half a byte. It's stack-based.

```
n        Push the context variable n, 1 in global scope
 ><      Push an empty compressed integer = 0
   ?(    Input times, do the following...
         Example with stack = [2, 3]
     :   Duplicate [2, 3, 3]
      }  Rotate stack right [3, 2, 3]
       + Add [3, 5]
         And the next pair is now on the stack
         The last one is implicitly output
```

Here, `n(}` take up one byte each, and `><?:+` take up half a byte each.

Answer (score 4):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$4\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ <s>4.125</s> 3.292 bytes

```
G:1'+
```

New language! Yay! This is a fractional byte language I've been advertising on TNB for a while now. It's pure printable ASCII, and has a <s>97</s> 96 char codepage. Although the spec is mostly written by now, this commit only has the bare minimum implemented for this challenge. To run this, check the README.
It will print Fibonacci numbers until your computer runs out of RAM. Explanation:

```
G1'+ - Takes no input
G    - Generate an infinite list using initial terms...
 1   - 1...
  '  - And the generating function...
   + - Addition (the initial terms are repeated to fit the arity)
```

Answer (score 4):

## C, 43 bytes

```
a;main(z){for(;;)printf("%d ",a=(z+=a)-a);}
```

[try it out](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/ROjcxM0@jSrM6Lb9Iw9pas6AoM68kTUNJNUVBSSfRVqNK2zZRUzdR09q69v9/AA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 36

```
f=lambda x:x>1and f(x-1)+f(x-2)or x
```

Answer (score 3):

#### J - 20

First *n* terms:

```
(+/@(2&{.),])^:n i.2
```

Answer (score 3):

## bash pur, 49 chars, third solution

```
r=0;l=1;echo -e {1..45}" $((r+=l)) $((l+=r))\n";
```

bash pur, 52 chars, second solution

```
r=0;l=1;echo -e {1..40}" "$((r+=l))" "$((l+=r))\\n;
```

former solution (60 chars):

```
r=0;l=1;for i in {1..40};do((r+=l));((l+=r));echo $r $l;done
```

Comment: Could be written: `r=1 l=0;echo -e {,,}{,,}{,,}" $[r+=l] $[l+=r]"`

Comment: ... And *former* version: `for((r=1,l=1;l<9**9;r+=l,l+=r)){ echo $r $l;}`

Comment: 34 chars: `for((a=1;b+=a;a+=b)){ echo $a $b;}`

Comment: @F.Hauri: My improved solution is only 1 char longer than yours, with preserving the line oriented output, while your solution doesn't reach the max possible value before integer overrun.

Comment: @roblogic: In my opinion, negative results are not acceptable, but with a halting condition like `for((a=1;b+=a;a+=b)){ echo $a $b;}|head -n46` your code is still 4 characters shorter than mine (improved one) - so why don't you publish your solution as an answer, or did you?

Comment: I published a `zsh` answer, which I wil have to correct :\

Comment: Ok, I finally posted [my (former) version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191048/9424) (inspired by your;)

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp, 48 Chars

```
(defun f(n)(if(< n 2) n(+(f(decf n))(f(1- n)))))
```

Comment: Is left-to-right evaluation order guaranteed in CL? If not, your solution won't work. (There is no such guarantee in Scheme, and many implementations are right-to-left.)

Comment: Left-to-right is in the standard so since these are all built-in functions it is reliable.  (Macros can of course do stupid things :-)

Comment: This is actually 47;  you can get rid of the space between (< n 2) and n.

Comment: And a slight modification is 46: `(defun f(n)(if(< n 2)n(+(f(1- n))(f(- n 2)))))`.

Answer (score 3):

### BrainFuck, 172 characters

```
>++++++++++>+>+[[+++++[>++++++++<-]>.<++++++[>--------<-]+<<<]>.>>[[-]<[>+<-]>>[<<+>+>-]<[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>[-]>+>+<<<-[>+<-]]]]]]]]]]]+>>>]<<<]
```

Credit goes to [Daniel Cristofani](http://www.hevanet.com/cristofd/brainfuck/fib.b)

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell: 42 or 75

**Find nth Fibonacci number - 42**

A spin-off of [Joey's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214/9387), this will take user input and output the nth Fibonacci number. This retains some weaknesses also inherent to Joey's original code:

> - Technically off by 1, since it starts the Fibonacci sequence at `1,1` instead of the more proper `0,1`.
> - Only valid for Fibonacci numbers which will fit into int32, because this is PowerShell's default type for integers.
> - Example: Due to the int32 limitation, the highest input that will return a valid report is 46 (1,836,311,903) and this is technically the 47th Fibonacci number since zero was skipped.

**Golfed:**

```
($b=1)..(read-host)|%{$a,$b=$b,($a+$b)};$a
```

**Un-Golfed & Commented:**

```
# Feed integers, from 1 to a user-input number, into a ForEach-Object loop.
# Initialize $b while we're at it.
($b=1)..(read-host)|%{
    # Using multiple variable assignment...
    # ...current $b is put into new $a, and...
    # ...sum of current $b and current $a are put into new $b.
    $a,$b=$b,($a+$b)
};
# When loop exits, output $a.
$a

# Variable cleanup, not included in golfed code.
rv a,b
```

---

**List Fibonacci numbers - 75**

Another derivative of [Joey's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214/9387), but with some improvements:

> - Zero is included in the output, as it should be according to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000045).
> - Goes up to the maximum Fibonacci number that can be handled as uint64 instead of the default int32. (Highest Fibonacci number in uint64 is 12,200,160,415,121,876,738.)
> - Output stops once the maximum value is reached, instead of looping through 'Infinity' or continuously throwing errors.

**Golfed:**

```
for($a,$b=0,1;$a+$b-le[uint64]::MaxValue){$a;$a,$b=$b,[uint64]($a+$b)}$a;$b
```

**Un-Golfed & Commented:**

```
# Start Fibonacci loop.
for
(
    # Begin with $a and $b at zero and one.
    $a,$b=0,1;

    # Continue so long as the sum fits in uint64.
    $a+$b-le[uint64]::MaxValue
)
{
    # Output current $a.
    $a;

    # Using multiple variable assignment...
    # ...current $b becomes new $a, and...
    # ...sum of current $b and current $a is forced to uint64 and stored in new $b.
    $a,$b=$b,[uint64]($a+$b)
}

# Output $a and $b one more time.
$a;$b

# Variable cleanup - not included in golfed code.
rv a,b
```

Comment: One thing that bugs me a little in PowerShell: `Read-Host` *always* reads interactively and won't pick up things you pipe into the script (or process), whereas `$input` (which is what I tend to use) *only* picks up piped input (for obvious reasons; that's how it's defined) but cannot be used interactively. Which means that you can write a PowerShell script that either works interactively or one that works with piped input, but not both at the same time (at least not for golfing).

Comment: Yeah, and I personally prefer my scripts to be interactive whether the challenge calls for it or not. Wait... Did you just golf the un-golfed code? And not just any part of it, but particularly the bit that's not at all in the golfed code?

Comment: I merely optimized it, since `Remove-Variable` takes a `string[]`. There is no need to have two calls ;-)

Comment: I meant to say I found it amusing that of all the code to be optimized, you had to go and fix the bit that wasn't even part of the golfed solution. It's like you had an OCD moment or something.

Comment: Sometimes I do ;-). I don't see anything that makes the golfed code smaller either. For an algorithm this simple there aren't many options and `range|%` is often the shortest (but also the slowest) way.

Answer (score 3):

### Whitespace, <s>50</s> 47

Replace S,T,L with Space,Tab,Linefeed:

```
SSSLSSSTLSLSTLSTLSSSLSLSSTSSTSLTSSSSLSTLSTLSLSL
```

Explanation:

```
push 0      SS SL
push 1      SS STL
dup         SLS
outn        TLST
lbl  0      LSS SL
dup         SLS
cpy  2      STS STSL
add         TSSS
dup         SLS
outn        TLST
jmp  0      LSL SL
```

Outputs all the Fibonacci numbers concatenated (the question didn't mention separating them :)

```
1123581321345589144233377610987159725844181676510946...
```

(Thanks to @KevinCruijssen for -3 bytes.)

Comment: Hmmm... When I posted this (the 60th answer), the question automatically became "community wiki" :(

Comment: Yes, this site automatically community-wikis any posts after the 60th answer. But as a mod, I can undo that, and I'm going through the laborious process of removing community-wiki from all the answers, one by one. :-P

Comment: I know it's been 4.5 years, but you can golf three bytes by changing `SS SSL` (push 0) to `SS SL` (push 0), `LSS SSL` (label_0) to `LSS SL` (label_0) and `LSL SSL` to `LSL SL` (jump to label_0). Pushing `0` is done implicitly after stating it's either positive/negative, even when you have no `S` and/or `T` for the binary part. [Try it online](https://tinyurl.com/y9dnrsf4) (or with just raw spaces/tabs/new-lines: [Try it online (**47 bytes**)](https://tinyurl.com/ycvs2833)). +1 from me, though. Nice answer!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - Thanks for the tip. When implementing it, I found and corrected an error that was causing the output to be 01235... instead of the intended 11235....

Answer (score 3):

### Forth - <del>38</del> 33 bytes

```
: f dup . 2dup + 2 pick recurse ;
```

Generates and prints a Fibonacci series recursively until it runs out of stack space.

Usage:

```
 1 1 f
```

---

Or to generate `Fn`, where n>=1 (66 bytes):

```
: f dup 3 < if 1 nip else dup 1- recurse swap 2 - recurse + then ;
```

Example of usage:

```
9 f .
```

output:

```
34
```

Comment: It does work, but like I said it doesn't terminate itself. It should generate correct output up until `46!` at least, and after that it will just keep on going and output "garbage". And since that online compiler doesn't appear to have any way of halting the execution without clearing the console output it gets pretty hard to see the correct output at the beginning.

Comment: So it just runs so fast that all I can see is the zeros?

Comment: Right. If you run it in Win32Forth you can scroll up and get it to stay at the top so that you actually can see the correct output for `Fn` up to `n=46`.

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken `: f over . 2dup + recurse ;` is shorter (27 bytes). This way, the first number is printed first, and the numbers are in order on the stack, so we don't need `2 pick`.

Comment: Yup, that seems to generate the same sequence as my version.

Comment: Since you're into Forth, you may find [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60839/34718) interesting. Since they're completely different from yours, I made my own answer instead of suggesting edits.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 41 bytes

There are a couple other Java answers here, but I'm surprised nobody has posted this simple one:

```
int f(int n){return n<2?n:f(n-1)+f(n-2);}
```

For an extra byte you can extend the range up to `long`.

Answer (score 3):

## [TeaScript](https://esolangs.org/wiki/TeaScript), 4 bytes

```
F(x)

F(x) //Find the Fibonacci number at the input
```

Compile online [here](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/?code=F(x)&input=6&v=1) (**DOES NOT WORK IN CHROME**). Enter input in the *first* input field.

Comment: This entry fails the [creating a compiler after a challenge has been posted](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5800/3) loophole and therefore isn't valid. I can't accept this answer, sorry.

Comment: With TeaScript 3, you can just do `Fß`.

Answer (score 3):

## J, 9 bytes

```
+/@:!&i.-
```

Gets the *n*<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number by finding the sums of the binomial coefficients C(*n-i*-1, *i*) for *i* from 0 to *n*-1.

Also, a short way using **12 bytes** to generate the first *n* Fibonacci numbers is

```
+/@(!|.)\@i.
```

It uses the same method as above but works by operating on prefixes of the range `[0, 1, ..., n-1]`.

#### Usage

```
   f =: +/@:!&i.-
   f 10
55
   f 17
1597
```

#### Explanation

```
+/@:!&i.- Input: n
        - Negate n
     &i.  Form the ranges [n-1, n-2, ..., 0] and [0, 1, ..., n-1] 
    !     Find the binomial coefficient between each pair of values
+/@:      Sum those binomial coefficients and return
```

Comment: Whoa. Just whoa.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 90 characters and just two variables

There was one before with 55 characters, but it used a variable without declaring it and had no output. This one has both and (the actual logic) is shorter. And as a little bonus it looks absolutely horrific code-style-wise and depends on compiler quirks, yay!

```
interface A{static void main(String[]x){for(int a,b=a=1;;System.out.println(b=a+(a=b)));}}
```

The special features I used are:

- Using an interface instead of a class. The program can still be run as normal, but I don't need to write "`public`" twice. This saves 10 characters
- Declaring multiple variables at once: `int a,b`;
- Initializing multiple variables at once and in the declaration, needs a second `a`: `b=a=1;`
- Everything is done in the `for` head, the body is empty: `for(...);`
  The first and third block of `for` are intended for variable initialization and variable incrementation, but they can hold any commands.
- The whole logic is inside the output: `System.out.println(b=a+(a=b))`
- Just two variables without recursion! This is done by using the way the compiler works: The assignment to `b` first reads the value of `a`, then it evaluates the right side of the `+`, where it reads the value of `b` and writes it into `a`, but the left side of the `+` still has the old value of `a` that gets added to the value of `b` after assigning the value of `b` to `a`. Then that sum gets written to `b` while `a` already holds the old value of `b`.
  I was lucky that the compiler works this way, because it could also have first evaluated the expression in the brackets, like for example C does, then it just lists all powers of 2 instead of the Fibonacci numbers.

In a dream programming language this would just be: `b=a+(a=b`

Comment: Dammit, referring to this answer just helped me in actually useful code, but I can't upvote it! :D

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, 28 Characters

```
f=n=>(n<=2)?1:f(n-1)+f(n-2);
```

[Try it here!](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/evjgjz)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! How about `n<3`? And do you really need the parentheses around the inequality? You can probably also omit the semicolon.

Comment: @MartinEnder is correct, use `f=n=>n<3?1:f(n-1)+f(n-2)` for a total of 24 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 100 bytes

```
➡️◀️2➕➖1➖2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9J/f9h/oRuhQ/zZzUBid52EHfah/lTFj2at/D9jn6QOEgYiLseTW8Ai0yYagQV6gNxgHQnEE@GiT2aNxWifxpI1hCJbQRV2vkfRHBxfZjf3wi2lEsBSE1pUshUeNS/0lDB0BgmChKf0QCSXAgiFgFVGBqAVQP1g00CAA)

Answer (score 3):

### [Piet](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html), 17 codels

Not sure how to count this one. There are 17 pixels within the code that count as instructions/control flow modifiers (18 if you count the required NOP to get the color back to the correct cycle for the loop).

Shown here at 20 pixels per codel:

[image: Short Fibonacci in Piet]

Explanation in pseudocode:

```
push 1
push 1
push 1
push 1
out (number)
out (number)
START OF INFINITE LOOP
duplicate
push 3
push 1
roll ; the last three instructions amount to "rotate the top to the third spot once"
add
duplicate
out (number)
END OF INFINITE LOOP
```

This outputs the Fibonacci sequence (starting with 1,1) without delimiters.

Actual image (way too small to see clearly):
[image: SMALLER Fibonacci in Piet]

Comment: Oh, didn't know there was a convention for this. Was unsure. Will change now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/), <s>42</s> 35 bytes

7 bytes thanks to Mario Carneiro.

```
def f:_->nat|(n+2):=f(n+1)+f n|x:=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lNzPv/PyU1TSHNKl7XLi@xpEYjT9tI08o2DUgbamqnKeTVVFjZVvxXTi1LzFFIUzAy4OJSLijKzCtRKChKTcusUEj7DwA)

---

Lean is a completely different kind of a programming language: it is a proof-assistant. That means, mathematical theorems can be formalized and proved in Lean, and mathematical objects can be constructed in Lean.

In this case, the auto-generated correctness theorems are (cf tio link):

```
f.equations._eqn_1 : f 0 = 0
f.equations._eqn_2 : f 1 = 1
f.equations._eqn_3 : ∀ (n : ℕ), f (n + 2) = f (nat.succ n) + f n
```

Comment: I had no idea anyone else knew about Lean.

Comment: "else" :o ... are you in the lean chat?

Comment: No, but the only reason I know it exists is because I know someone who contributed to it

Comment: @qwr might I know him?

Comment: If you know Jeremy Avigad

Comment: @qwr I don't talk to him much on the Lean chat, but I've seen this name

Comment: Is this a code golf chat or on another site?

Comment: @qwr it's the official Lean chat https://leanprover.zulipchat.com and has no affiliation with codegolf

Comment: I didn't know that existed, huh. Do you work with or on Lean? I've heard of some theorems being formalized but not much else.

Comment: @qwr I'm a volunteer that contributes to mathlib, a library of Lean

Answer (score 3):

## [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar), 19 bytes

```
@\
#_+_1
!_:.
9>$!,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJT8pLLPr/3yGGSzleO96QSzHeSo/L0k5FUef///@6KQA)

Generates the sequence with no end, separating each number with a tab.

---

*One year later...*

I should probably check if I've already answered a question before I start coding...

Anyway, here's an alternative 19 byter that outputs in the same way, only 1-indexed this time and without the leading tab.

## [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar), 19 bytes

```
!\$\@
:>+_,9
+ <>$.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJT8pLLPr/XzFGJcaBy8pOO17HkktbwcZORe////@6KQA)

Comment: +1 for 'I should probably check if I've already answered a question'

Answer (score 3):

## C++, 42 bytes

I haven't read every solution in this challenge, but the leaderboard doesn't have a C++ solution, which is a travesty.

```
int f(int i){return i-->1?f(i)+f(i-1):!i;}
```

Comment: You can save 1 byte by getting rid of the `--`, making it ``f(i-1)+f(i-2)`` and then (that's where you save the byte) ``!i`` can be just ``i``.

Answer (score 3):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
~1~ +
AB~/!
^ +/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcoxDsIwDEbhPaf4mStU9Qa0GxNLZyQTDLVE4yhxhi45OqE9AXrf@B5ifvMfbq0OFZ0bp9qf3B1d34Zx@t/FzYtk7EyRODIZCJ6TkQTQqiUY9AWTlTMoPI8vm0bM1xs4UZbwhi0MLRaLta9GEw25ncsP)

Outputs the 0 based sequence. This could be 14 bytes:

```
~1~+
AB~!
^ +/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcoxDsIwDEbhPaf4mSuEegPajYmlM5IJhlqidpQ4A0uOToAToPeN7yoeX/HJvbexDWGa2y5cMBz6OM3/O4ZllYIvN2ROTA5C5OwkCtqsqsPucNm4gPT2@4pbwnI6gzMV0Qd8ZVj1VL2/LbmYlr6vHw)

But it prints an extra `0` in front of the sequence, which takes a couple of bytes to fix...

There's also a 17 byte solution:

```
v0<
AB~
~ +\
~  !
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hYqxDsIwDAX3fMVjRkiwM9BuTCwdWUww1BKNo9ipxNJPJ5QvQHe66W7i8R1f3Nq8P4auX8KC7XUNNu3Q9f85hWEUw6orCmcmByFycZIEmrQmhz7gMrGB0v33mWvGcL6AC5mkJ3xkaPVcvX00u2iytqtf)

Which I like because you can switch between 0-based and 1-based just by changing the [`0` on the first line to a `1`](https://tio.run/##hYqxDsIwDAX3fMVjRgzdGWg3JpaOLCYYaonGUeJUYumnY8oXoDvddDex@I4vdl@6Y@iHNazYX7dg510//OcUxkkqNk1RODMZCJGLkSTQrC0Z9AGTmSso3X9fNc0YzxdwoSrpCZsY2iw3849mE03VD@0L).

For both solutions, the numbers are infinitely output is in unary 1 bits separated by 0 bits. The `-u` flag converts the unary numbers to decimal instead, but the TIO tends to cut off the outputting section sometimes, and the last number is always truncated too. There's a bit in the footer to prevent this.

#### Explanation:

Basically, these solutions only use a single pair of collectors and distinguishes between the two numbers by storing one as unary `1` bits and the other as unary `0` bits.

This starts off with `1` being pushed to the collectors to initialise the sequence.

```
~ ~    Invert the whole stack
AB~    This basically swaps the values of the two numbers
       Also duplicate a copy downwards and rightwards
```

```
       Split the stream into zeroes and ones with the plus
!  /!  Print a single 0 as the separator
^ +/   And add a copy of the 1s to the collector
```

```
  ~ +
    !  Print a copy of the 1s to the output
```

This repeats infinitely, basically executing the pseudocode:

```
a=0
b=1
while 1:
    oldA = a
    b,a = a,b
    print ','
    a += oldA
    print oldA
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 36 bytes

I'm a total idiot. I didn't even think of this formula!

```erlang
f(X)when X<2->1;f(X)->f(X-1)+f(X-2).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5z/U/TSNCszwjNU8hwsZI187QGsTXtQOSuoaa2iDKSFPvf25iZp5GdCxQIjPfqrwosyRVI03DTBMoAwA)

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 50 bytes

```erlang
f(X,Y)->io:write(X),io:nl(),f(Y,X+Y).
f()->f(1,1).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5z/U/TSNCJ1JT1y4z36q8KLMkVSNCUwfIzsvR0NRJ04jUidCO1NTjStMAKknTMNQx1NT7n5uYmacRHQsWAXIB)

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 51 bytes

Tail-recursion optimized.

```erlang
f(0,X,_)->X;f(I,X,Y)->f(I-1,Y,X+Y).
f(X)->f(X,1,1).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5z/U/TcNAJ0InXlPXLsI6TcMTyI4EsoEsXUOdSJ0I7UhNPa40jQiwWISOoY6hpt7/3MTMPI3oWKBYZr5VeVFmSapGmoaZJlAGAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry), 54 bytes

```
<>{<>(){}(<>())}{{}[<>{<>(){}{}[<><<>()>]}{({})}]{{}}}
```

This is an anonymous function that takes a number \$n\$ as a Church numeral and pushes \$F_n\$ to the stack as a Church numeral.

It can be tested by invoking the interpreter as follows:

```
$ ./Flurry -inn -c '<>{<>(){}(<>())}{{}[<>{<>(){}{}[<><<>()>]}{({})}]{{}}}{}' 10
55
```

Note that this is very slow for large inputs (>30 or so) because Church numeral addition is \$O(n)\$.

### Explanation

The basic idea is to loop \$n\$ times and keep track of the smaller number using the stack and the larger number using function parameters, so the function to iterate looks like this:

```
next = λb. pop() + push(b)
```

Flurry is mostly combinator-based, and so doesn't really have lambdas. The closest approximation is to write a function that pushes its argument onto the stack (using the `{...}` monad) and then pops from the stack to read the argument back (using the `{}` nilad). So the function `λx. f x` gets represented as:

```
{ f {} }
```

However, this translation doesn't work if `f` depends on the stack, which is true in this case, so we need to use a combinator-based approach instead. Rather than popping using `{}` directly, we can write an anonymous function that ignores its argument and returns a value popped from the stack:

```
  λa. pop()
{ <> () {} {} }
```

Here, `<>` and `()` represent the S and K combinators respectively.

Of course, the next thing we do with the popped value is apply it to the successor function `<><<>()>` to compute addition:

```
  λa. pop()(suc)
{ <> () {} {} [<><<>()>] }
```

Now all we need is to write a function that pushes its argument to the stack and returns it unchanged:

```
  λa. push(a)
{ ({}) }
```

We can then put these functions together using the S combinator:

```
  λb. pop() + push(b)
  λb. S (λb. pop()(suc)) (λb. push(b)) b
<> {<>(){}{}[<><<>()>]} {({})}
```

The main function is responsible for setting up the initial values and calling `next` the appropriate number of times. In other words, it looks like this:

```
main = λn. push(0); n (next) (1)
```

Since we don't care about the return value, we can just use function application to sequence the two actions:

```
main = λn. push(0) (n (next) (1))
```

Again, we can't keep lambda variables on the stack because we're already doing stack manipulation, so we'll have to create intermediate functions. First, one that ignores its argument and pushes `0` to the stack:

```
  λa. push(0)
{ <> () {} (0) }
```

Second, one that applies its argument to `next` and `1` (which we can finally use stack lambdas for):

```
  λa. a next 1
{ {} next 1 }
```

Again, we can put these together with `S`:

```
<> {<>(){}(0)} {{}[next]1}
```

Substituting the definitions of `0`, `next`, and `1` gives us the final result:

```
<>{<>(){}(<>())}{{}[<>{<>(){}{}[<><<>()>]}{({})}]{{}}}
```

Comment: Is it some kind of functional brain-flak? :D

Comment: @Bubbler Pretty much.

Comment: Given the git description is "Brain-flak, but functional.", I'd say yes

Comment: I just opened a [chat room for Flurry](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111736/flurry).

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 36 bytes

Infinitely outputs the fibonacci sequence. Also see [@Razetime's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229027/88546) for a recursive version which outputs the nth number.

```red
a: b: 1
forever[print a b: a + a: b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@z/RSiHJSsGQKy2/KLUstSi6oCgzr0QhESSYqKCtAJKO/f8fAA)

#### [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 36 bytes

An alternative 36.

```red
a: 1 b: 0
forever[print b: a + a: b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@z/RSsFQIclKwYArLb8otSy1KLqgKDOvBCSUqKCtAJROiv3/HwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/index.html), <s>17</s> 13 bytes

(non-recursive version)

*Edit: -4 bytes thanks to hints from ovs*

```
{⊑+´⊸∾⟜⊏⍟↕2}
```

[Try it at BQN online REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RmliIOKGkCB74oqRK8K04oq44oi+4p+c4oqP4o2f8J2VqeKGlTJ9CkZpYsKoIOKGlTIw)

---

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/index.html), 17 bytes

(recursive version)

```
{>1?+´¨-1‿2;}
```

[Try it at BQN online REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RmliIOKGkCB78J2VqT4xPyvCtPCdlYrCqPCdlaktMeKAvzI78J2VqX0KRmliwqgg4oaVMjAK)

Comment: The second version can be simplified if you only keep track of the last two values instead of the entire sequence (one-indexed algorithm: Start with `0‿1 ≡ ↕2`; ``-times join sum and first element; Return first value of final pair)

Comment: @ovs - Thanks for the hints!    Much better now.

Answer (score 3):

## Hexagony - 61 bytes, return seperator

```
))')).............../{\/{\)))/=.(\=.+\\*{/..==..\>{;"!<.({("/
```

[Try it online!](https://hexagony.net/#lzN4Igxg9gJgpiBcICUSDkKB0Xs9wemAB1CDiUk8BeDACmOoGpjiAqYPLS6jYgPmADchEAEIAPLWB0QeEABoQASwB2ABwCuAFwQgGARkLKGAJnlK1WgLLQ4iAIYAnAOYgAvkA=)

Comment: You know you can use digits for numbers too, right?

Answer (score 3):

## [Seed](https://github.com/TryItOnline/seed), <s>4694</s> 4502 bytes

```
39 23345386873944734309285705649562214322923535338513787840726059344836991733232701124858784406171983413525769035739193091317312821286862091673034093258254737808529480740867073160694207283540732802589654087348246306424108351751311067631335648365532710947883728455312678903999543414986443810435493370315134647072481870757046559560767136040676281671376819795324434856453735428264762843673716931661746853554648863000837820618766325590788356124601042099541341483064315601051750207795784533758073620813013115058115202328602261019521188162907432705317709462265407997435677959431637608739188384820535674569023665708824769117130584628086812767619300150936306513016713438624735631896208226558553705578499273228365561706607508974248633654644472401969256417949202545503229189330457914013293106347633234904257897628188377211123547522316430704423351649833550317940803484242023657434716958957587230473447472170005697587796499855927956924703860969370032077181183813997697920001129271041258462117064842855557817828287309864524148521039064850419014169734078927801370682493891194692916817142423371375512874755307643229558474820620773013367601053438535142499961672800471263088573030714197841432529737819978024272023115971994335629080760807110601625840500005576870897474597727212673444634680054468191797452281171657965522840129388173724585980135600170025063620602628298627811946062091546889131371926823568681212834659514998682306098670560578318063077703702015608052686405555782215469820110984687203004291914156230320625462064509758167591458209331235212640744714944466265540624319127738893716421169144022527159634296736260757337640921918849758954315864968212488657203226533587353649351778992581839569265033006103790337825946891770665589403131544197363786202809251067880755092540881383788858825619755294045426872602952477879200662412263820311579658891410984567942455376104064634087560919309116469779337448222971714205506106434861563361065264676346668562754032388044586603191705003186050941101737238753507972188516844227916598403811945061789829209022797794856907795280845148337927336190754837895578035971541077446106601429711198909985434167448288125565008326994953358507196336677928811063398215196756813330927829954298340363790942335608247284708980931664255175263323494474655761771711383684020341286483311232450751637188832338282365001980619004736926421020545780168645284628043949398052855672494054844858796879547004560821501647027627620931639915989753539985160519138882067784198444595441811191399424880792691274895217945599103951284792036009843684640644727200173221626567038906492094115422297154223582626065131092394499833564570471955561529154762920901660552470118203300492660926353444889031479441391716424199093929419050805652092712224713014163928963683320445942834620765638299957157761471954992453965174566767052457734421384797861892548612233678879032571407415763995799697084460449481011980933595196444998930307697403672188673825999360332797937744985054511100836407779016165673872373310879592118399300133957780585475517066306666920397584925551254210311998315301028471463539416320653567122160674748915331494295984381121190145666938252633808615711556028673805375510446823318750130981978154654997326727239404525161535622829359058005003740269566983082692378752252198224696254750416200980706704359975518565261545420238758226454680563033057001226125143840414367435620075434502664984902148647078854467653648067041037379150849558209574954581189083630370505506375071080959718696461782683034278484505125465265492405192125616634322283908654348532913099106491870966062276727286614470801650571178850146397543614007581120988735292604484768834605242986004904531743614154630006898576385883749714930636531225280325429278056803694383205579251797535306160456389603169599349989707250713018909969811190663566801819447003975601708056252841800628364818930316430260043879135073603348919031644234002981192629576497660461677947610006543231706577837438811265977164354969644885825582261812180155492583995120383156018469389467006878690072374841382066122175919585112489442594496493463386891710103741087324632245353507660394419350165419526162955982962335197477336304033108148298040661871462588450794544521467248068540365914505422139306015926783904272029251862004795498004645359369772500371366215160030879374914060894959826814924777847813129579229461420328680050563398486579073401384070598971755243256100966805691895631455236232588087146040702221938793149485419052426135144305222421870942178316091451568136489010664122415628294236744095902991276097097917
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LdiJlV03DAPQVlKC9if2E1eQ/s/kQuM4sTN/kUgQAPH8358///78zPpnzLn2vOd@s9b65pqtxt1f22fVPmP0NceoMbdf8@4@v/vd1b5x2q651p2nqn9zjjm@1vtYd@cTq53@9bpz9bnH/k61uV3Syw19@kYfd/jv3DO8cr7Z5mo1x75jq@S77e5R67ZvtXu@5hunnVrD5XduNcxxm4/X8YMG1h3rzHbWWL35RP@U23s735l9Th0pdm919lbru3c6aHmhj/Nd9VXVXgpedc9a8/a23FNzfm12Z62zlKHDfv0JpOU4KLXvfH2etnLVuD0/fef2@sptToLJAfPnNE07xafW1PLXT2kLVOtcEG9X3KuJpoHvDiDe7xyg7GqpeB8In6YyoKm2p9ybplWY19N1A5GrTcHMvg3BCePbZwseu@3r99FM7J42xumt1x69X6UP96yMEizfByccCL5fldf3ycHlsqPDgF6@NS/ofcG7axv0mOdA55qHuXc8mO50kpGCZYDrhAdNLTUzsp3aAhvUj285anaDVXWu39eUlJSWqobBjzdKuLUD/t2u6gzmTC/DEJXH0tWpAfn@1Sr9bsNuobOj52xrf9V9ag4zaGcqNjReBVw31ZtlWPLBppPA@vYYWicSs1@0s/2A4zPn5pZ2kfiqJOjCwOgzYhzd5vANl@Lp@pSn9EZllde/ckxpUm/4VBBogGjq17aSzbMbGqQ7lgL100@L3CpsXn08fHvwyP2OClgdhfwirTB6j3DFoDE9H9u@V60vBSoKvZx1weEMk6t5jc78C16m9vW0hU8@sDfhasJUcP85hBlpK4xNsWEafj9CZqa4ka8T2DFmPIAD1U0c2RF@czq53BW7ofrIv2uUvtf4AibGFj9BPdxAUqQ@@S36Rp3033YLpLyGPEMIbCzDgzWBg507kJmP@D/HG5hPoFIYalh8JD9hBELQgiLGQr0KKMTVMrKxMUWPhIMeA65Aezi152PYd28MDlA1AOmbj/QQczu76Bl13nBGxdgcbVb47mTYGf1HwZHzbdsRR2dvnNzY8QVkXZeBYxTs0JWtAhAwM2SBxkqJi7zQC@Lb23yV2maIHEAMHBEVE1xORMa@BmUXgX76r7jTwikSZufDXD5DgOGoE0eJ8Bg/AtgZPUawcl08tG9V14nBx8926oyQDQ8b9/Rm/BnlCJTI5mP9oSLt8KP5seMYIK854PyicxSjMMhCIWzhHF@WBzo5JT5/EYIU/USJpBIPxTBGxCrUln1C9msEORPkeksRT0wwICOcBFPYFjpkkutBzdpsniwL1hWjD5f4nyH9XWmwoqMv28JWHCTxPc2YXTo62QLHiOjCT@a6spdAz/hxSMW8RwPLoHha5vCF0XiBH4zYzB8lp1vnZsh4rTnaZEV8A4UVyjfCxtwJXQQ19Ja3lZY1VG81xInXzuaAND9Vkzf2CmAVqlnW6rdffBw/emxWM15zul0Zt8qqPK9ZWNtQxmdrDXlAdMikFcmCHZ6tkQ/FZaeiLFMUIgwukcBh0FlmI3GhZawuePZKAiZEkxG0MWdXMucsufHXrOOmJ6JHEoBn6BAhINXZb2kx5m12GszaApoqhRnynalZQy39x5vDQpz3dcsibniecf4uryUjlfqpksHyMbf7HPyTedAdsirFsNRtufUEBusu/77imTcJ8abEqWAo0sBC0TfW@cUBDREHKhy/QTuOn92G24qLOtfNujZPC6Pi5rHjFRYLIWFrEDgh6Yr7xbior0fkJ4sl7h9eoBTQH1Pzp4mNqDrbGOlHEmG97QaCL46NGoRERT6vpcctE0HxbCz7aTwBO9yLftOkXm6yVVefjuSF5yraNONpt2QH7TgdTYQKNOiw5IEVvIYUoB2zjjIAERe1YrQywxqLlVZN/5WXdCD0kG5PFKEwGvLKF/sfYFYFz7D/WYQ/NT1jG7EbO7/HFB2XOTEA6xfv0N/VxEN//ZFwxsUrKQM89daXT4a5T5LMMcZVog04Ij1WSifGHVaZaXQSAyYL@PWMZSYdEKLkmoSVNKaIZCSKUT@AbgLIfpHH7vBPBh7HhffOSt5hLrZnaN1qRuMbi88cKmii2EtpPWxAt2xss3Sr/rhhqINzLk8u2LkirURqiW6QwRjkHq9Hqz31tGxTOEqqGJ@okU2eTZVxYN4JCedzXjbtlGzw7E446qo9lwMfcrtS7cSjtzxp7GwdoKPEqay1L6HF/N0ig5muTFpx9n5DIIfH3tszyUTHlX2MWzPEROIWi4eUnMEkEjfOi7VO/GJosvNJpBMCPfrcF/iZ7IpZZ23dd2cWFJOicB/cb7HKeuiXZI3tN6E2gfWZP5QYIYpXPPVqZMWcLaE88jA/DuKTmV9agJrsimCWJ7UZdgIW3jv37PcwIbEG6MpaqTyM1En8SLAGtfVhYWMubjnXzNJCCw8qTXo33WbQYMw@puRwHFmEF/qKZhJtImVTE23ftzLTPJrYyDciyWY1uEqKmIlFeZQaWS4zXHxxksnThdjGc5PNsqm/X/9juideyZCy70wf4Z@k8pQVzFD47RqkiBOG@BiiLxRLh4/@J7ksF@Vmnqm@PB3kKS3afHF9pBWcANvO0xA2hPn13rZpADJyBxzIQKKRsdWWsMq2svKdCjo5FOsiR30nIwpSyZi5xNwy2pXAMfZjX0/uU@7OTHcEbcoM@PdZjUcnZKNWIGVLVlBMwBx6UsiJP/VkNw8Q@z1a6zqRaOV5wZxmntzjqC2MzFMvuXl5xARfSEiSiO/SWtiw8qB38pRndVDgec8wicrJAJ5O2nMgzAdHYk6ePxFH8eFoVg4XpowsP1q4iS3npcuWFcLfE2vtuDxSzzxJJb1n6Elqdkg8OvE/z8ObQyagP/17gD4JBiY144EhFqLapIkTFbn0KOPLkuQvqBaPtr2MaSVf3pftI3Y7eiV1yjQzD3j5C4v29m5PCMwzRkZa53lDHgfzvGmdCgQjfwPB7dJ2y/doD3ypKC5591tY9HF6HmqQa2djjSdDfyTJJxQy@hdwEJGZQjLp8mV02KJcklMcATrZ6b7i@wj6/fz8Dw)

Answer (score 3):

## [rSNBATWPL](https://github.com/Radvylf/rSNBATWPL), 28 bytes

```
n~cond{n<2}{1}${n- 1}+{n- 2}
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJyYWlzaW4tYmF0d2FmZmxlIixudWxsLCJmPW5+Y29uZHtuPDJ9ezF9JHtuLSAxfSt7bi0gMn07IiwiZiQ1IiwiIiwiIl0=)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 23 bytes

```r
repeat show(F<-T+(T=F))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRKE4I79cw81GN0RbI8TWTVPz/38A)

Similar to, but shorter than, [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89653/67312), prints the sequence indefinitely. Based on [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247838/67312) to a related challenge. Thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen) for some golfs.

Answer (score 3):

## [Chocolate](https://github.com/Steffan153/chocolate), 4 bytes

```
G+c1
```

[Try it online!](https://chocolate-lang.netlify.app/#WyJHK2MxIiwiIl0=)

### Explanation

```
G+c1
G     ## Generate an infinite list...
 +    ## With the addition function
  c1  ## Starting from [1, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 16 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{⊃⊃(+/,⊃)⍤⊢/⍵/1}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=c3vUNqH6UVczEGlo6@sAKc1HvUsedS3Sf9S7Vd@wFgA&f=e9Q39VHbBLdDKx71bjYyAAA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Straightforward "repeatedly add previous two elements" style approach. Not as short as [using pascal's triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence/223225#223225), but I'm still pretty proud of this :-)

-1 thanks to [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m) for reminding me of the atop operator, also known as the "atoperator". Also from Adám, an optional "full program" version of this for -2:

```
⊃⊃(+/,⊃)⍤⊢/⎕/1
```

Code breakdown:

```
{⊃⊃(+/,⊃)⍤⊢/⍵/1} full dfn
             ⍵/1  make a list of n 1s
            /      reduce over them with the following tacit function
          ⍤⊢       apply the following tacit function(?) to only the
                   previous element (in js, think (a,b)=>f(a))
    (  , )          return a list of
     +/               sum of elements ([5,3]=>8)
        ⊃             first element ([5,3]=>5)
                      ⍝([5,3]=>[8,5])
                   after the reduce, you're left with
                   a scalar of the value [fib(n),fib(n-1)]
  ⊃                take the first element of this scalar (the array)
 ⊃                 take the first element of the array (this is the end result)
```

As you can see, I'm still learning how APL works :P

If there are any terminology fixes you want to make in my explanation, go ahead; You have my blessing.

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 41 bytes

#### Code in ticker:

```
l->join(l,l[L]+l[L-1])
```

#### Code not in ticker

```
l=[1,1]
L=l.length
```

[Try it online](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xvokybqceh)

Answer (score 3):

### Dyalog APL, 17 characters (17 bytes SBCS)

```
{({⍵,+/¯2↑⍵}⍣⍵)⍺}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v1qj@lHvVh1t/UPrjR61TQSyax/1LgZSmo96d9X@T3vUNuFRb9@jvqme/o@6mg@tNwYp6psaHOQMJEM8PIP/GyqkKRiZAgA)

The arguments are the initial sequence on the left, and the number of additional terms to generate on the right. The call can be made shorter by [replacing](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v1qj@lHvVh1t/UPrjR61TQSyax/1LgZSmoa1/9MetU141Nv3qG@qp/@jruZD641BSvqmBgc5A8kQD8/g/2kKRqYA) the `⍺` with `1`, but then it can't generate an arbitrary sequence, only the one the question is actually about. Incidentally, replacing the `+` with a `-` will [produce the other half of the sequence](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v1qj@lHvVh1d/UPrjR61TQSyax/1LgZSmo96d9X@T3vUNuFRb9@jvqme/o@6mg@tNwYp6psaHOQMJEM8PIP/GygYKqQpGJkCAA).

As a bonus, the Java answer mentions Binet's formula (with rounding), which I [happened to have already written down](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v/pRT5eeqbbGo96tWo96V2g/6phxePuj3sW2QI6h5uHtplp6prX/0x61TXjU2/eob6qn/6Ou5kPrjR@1TQTygoOcgWSIh2fw/zSFR72bjUwB) (23 characters):

```
{⌊.5+(⍵*⍨+∘÷⍣=⍨1)÷5*.5}
```

Comment: I believe you can use an APL-specific character encoding that would make the characters equal the bytes: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/9429#9429

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms Thanks! After changing the encoding, the more extensible form of the solution is the same length and so can be at the top, which is great.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 2):

### Python

```
a,b,n=0,1,10
while n:a,b,n=b,a+b,n-1;print b
```

Comment: `a=b=1<newline>while 1:print a;a,b=b,a+b` 30 Characters

Comment: @st0le that's actually 31 characters. I've spent like 5 minutes recounting my solution, which is identical to yours, until I came to the conclusion you are wrong :)

Comment: The fibonacci sequence starts with 0. So you can't do `a=b=1`. It should be something like `a,b=0,1\nwhile 1:print a;a,b=b,a+b` which is 33 characters.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP - <s>109</s> <s>97</s> <s>88</s> 49 characters

```
<?for($a=$b++;;$b+=$a=$b-$a){$s+=$b%2*$b;echo$a;}
```

Comment: I have confirmed this works without using the optional parameters, but what exactly are they for?

Comment: @Bass5098: So that the function works when called in a unary context, I presume. If PHP uses JS-style argument passing where you can supply fewer arguments than the function declares, and you can perform meaningful computations involving `undefined` (or the PHP equivalent thereof), then cool!

Answer (score 2):

Python, 34 chars first variant, 31 chars for second variant,

```
a,b=1,1
while 1:print a;a,b=b,a+b
```

Second variant:

```
f=lambda x:x<2 or f(x-2)+f(x-1)
```

Comment: You can remove the space between `2` and `or`

Answer (score 2):

### Python O(1) Nth number, 91 char

48 characters for the import, a newline, 42 for the rest. I know it's longer than most here and that the question is a bit old, but I looked through the answers and I didn't see any that use the constant-time floating-point calculation.

```
from math import trunc as t,pow as p,sqrt as s
r=s(5);i=(1+r)/2;f=lambda n:t(p(i,n)/r+.5)
```

From there you call `f(n)` for the nth number in the sequence. Eventually it loses precision, and is only accurate up through `f(70)` (190,392,490,709,135). `i` is the constant Phi.

Comment: actually it's O(log n) since `pow` has that complexity...

Comment: @JBernado and even bigger since pow for bigint is more complicated story.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 51 (Loopless)

The following code uses Binet's formula to give the Nth Fibonacci number without using any loops.

```
print((($p=5**.5/2+.5)**($n=<>)-(-1/$p)**$n)/5**.5)
```

Comment: The second term starts small and only becomers smaller later on, so it can always be replaced by integer rounding. Golfing that a bit gives 30 byes: `say.5+(.5+5**.5/2)**<>/5**.5|0`

Answer (score 2):

Perl - 39 chars

```
($a,$b)=($b,$a+$b||1),print"$b
"while$=
```

Answer (score 2):

**Mathematica,26 chars**

```
If[#>1,#0[#-1]+#0[#-2],#]&
```

Comment: Damn, and I just thought I had come up with a new shortest Fibonacci implementation in Mathematica. +1 :)

Comment: What does the trailing `&` do?

Comment: @Cyoce making it a function, instead of an expression

Answer (score 2):

## C#

#### Generated as a stream (65 chars):

```
IEnumerable<int>F(){for(int c=1,s=1;;){s+=c=s-c;yield return c;}}
```

Could be reduced to 61 characters using non-generic `IEnumerable`.  Of course, if you include the required `System.Collections.Generic`, then it's a few more characters.

Answer (score 2):

## APL: 26 characters

This is a function which will print out the `n` and `n-1` Fibonacci numbers:

```
{({⍵+.×2 2⍴1 1 1 0}⍣⍵)0 1}
```

For example,

```
{({⍵+.×2 2⍴1 1 1 0}⍣⍵)0 1}13
```

yields the vector:

```
233 144
```

Comment: Surely, with APL's prodigious operator vocabulary, it should be able to compete in size with the GolfScript one? ;-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Oh probably, but I only started learning APL today...

Comment: Utilizing Pascal's triangle {+.!∘⌽⍨¯1+⍳⍵}

Answer (score 2):

### F# - 42 chars

```
Seq.unfold(fun(a,b)->Some(a,(b,a+b)))(0,1)
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `Seq.unfold`! =)

Answer (score 2):

## [JAGL](https://github.com/globby/Jagl) V1.0 - 13 / 11

```
1d{cdc+dcPd}u
```

Infinite Fibonacci sequence. Or, if not required to print:

11 bytes

```
1d{cdc+cd}u
```

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 26 chars

```
f=@(n)([1 0]*[1 1;1 0]^n)(2)
```

Basically, a copy of my solution from [Calculating (3 + sqrt(5))^n exactly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48779/calculating-3-sqrt5n-exactly/48788#48788).

[image: [a b] x [1 1 ;1 0] equals [a+b a]]

, so

[image: [f(1) f(0)] x [1 1 ;1 0]^n equals [f(n+1) f(n)]]

It's a disaster to do unnecessary* loops in Octave/Matlab. It's neither elegant, nor fast, let alone golfy.

---

*All loops that can be vectorized are unnecessary :).

Comment: I don't think you need the `[1 0]`. Picking the second item out of the matrix will give you the right number anyway.

Comment: Thank you for notice, `f=@(n)([1 1;1 0]^n)(3)` is six characters shorter indeed (Octave enumerates items in matrix top-down and then left-right when indexing with a single number, so the value at first row, second index is at index 3).

Answer (score 2):

## ArnoldC, 451 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE a
YOU SET US UP 1
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE b
YOU SET US UP 1
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE c
YOU SET US UP 1
STICK AROUND c
TALK TO THE HAND a
GET TO THE CHOPPER a
HERE IS MY INVITATION a
GET UP b
ENOUGH TALK
TALK TO THE HAND b
GET TO THE CHOPPER b
HERE IS MY INVITATION b
GET UP a
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER c
HERE IS MY INVITATION 1e300
LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET a
ENOUGH TALK
CHILL
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

This is actually my first ArnoldC program. Horrible for golfing, but great for lolz!

Produces an stream of Fibonacci numbers up to 1.1253474885494065e+274.

### Explanation

```
IT'S SHOWTIME               #start program

HEY CHRISTMAS TREE a        #declare a...
YOU SET US UP 1             #and set it to 1
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE b        #declare b...
YOU SET US UP 1             #and set it to 1
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE c        #declare c...
YOU SET US UP 1             #and set it to 1

STICK AROUND c              #while c is truthy
TALK TO THE HAND a          #output a
GET TO THE CHOPPER a        #assign a to...
HERE IS MY INVITATION a     #a...
GET UP b                    #plus b
ENOUGH TALK                 #end assignment
TALK TO THE HAND b          #output b
GET TO THE CHOPPER b        #assign b to...
HERE IS MY INVITATION b     #b...
GET UP a                    #plus a
ENOUGH TALK                 #end assignment
GET TO THE CHOPPER c        #assign c to...
HERE IS MY INVITATION 1e300 #whether 1e300...
LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET a #is greater than a (returns 0 or 1)
ENOUGH TALK                 #end assignment
CHILL                       #end while

YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED    #end program
```

Answer (score 2):

### Burlesque, 8 bytes

*Update*: With current WIP one can use `1J2q?+C~`.

Shortest way to produce `[fib(0)..fib(n)]` without trashing the stack (14B):

```
{0 1q?+#RC!}RS
```

**Explanation**

There's the concept of "Continuation" in Burlesque which basically means that
you run a function on a stack without destroying the stack. Fibonacci is the perfect example use-case for what these continuations are good for. If you have a program like `1 1 add` then this results in a stack of `2` because add destroys the data. If add were not to destroy the data the stack would look like `1 1 2` and if we just do `1 1 add add` it would look like `1 1 2 3`. So all we need to do to generate a Fibonacci sequence is to call add n-times without popping the arguments. A continuation takes a snapshot of the stack, runs the function, pops the result from the stack, reverts the stack to the snapshot and pushes the result of the function to it. `C!` is the Burlesque built-in for "run this continuation n-times". However, doing so would trash our stack (which is no problem if you just want to print out Fibonacci numbers). Otherwise we need to use the `RS` built-in which runs a function in a different stack environment. `RS` takes a value as an argument, creates an empty stack, pushes that value to it and then runs the given function on that stack and after the function has run it will collect that stack into a list and push that list to the main stack. `#R` rotates the stack because the stack layout will look like `N 0 1` but we need that `N` because it's the argument for `C!` so we rotate the stack. `q?+` is just shorthand for `{?+}` (q wraps the next token into a block).

If you don't care about trashing the stack you just drop the `RS`:

```
blsq ) 10 0 1q?+#R!C
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
```

[Try it online here](http://104.167.104.168/~burlesque/burlesque.cgi?q=1Jq%3F%2B100C!).

Shortest way to produce fib(n) as a reusable non stack-trashing piece of code I can think of is (17B):

```
0 1{Jx/?+}#RE!jvv
```

## Older Stuff

There's dozens of ways to do that. These push the fibonacci numbers to the
stack:

```
blsq ) 0 1{#s2.+++}10E!
blsq ) 0 1q?+10C!
```

However, the snippets above will also trash your stack. Alternatives for that are either:

```
blsq ) 0 1{Jx/?+}10E!jvv
```

which just computes the 10th fibonacci number.
Also by still using continuations you can let the whole thing run in a seperate stack environment like uhm so:

```
blsq ) {10}{0 1q?+#RC!}rs
{89 55 34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1 1 0}
blsq ) 10{0 1q?+#RC!}RS
{89 55 34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1 1 0}
```

Really depends on your needs.

Comment: This is [tag:code-golf], so please post the shortest solution you can find with its byte count.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 28 bytes

```
->f{loop{f<<p(f[-1]+f[-2])}}
```

Usage:

```
->f{loop{f<<p(f[-1]+f[-2])}}[[-1,1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## , 3 chars / 6 bytes (noncompetitive)

```
Мȫï
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=true&input=3&code=%D0%9C%C8%AB%C3%AF)</kbd>

More builtins!

`math.js + numbers.js = hella functions`

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, 23 bytes

22 bytes, plus 1 for `-nE` instead of `-e`.

```
say$.-=$b+=$.*=-1;redo
```

[Hat tip.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PerlGolf)

Comment: Is there an old version of Perl in which this worked? Because when I try it, it just outputs `-1` repeatedly in a tight loop. Also I don't understand the hat tip; there appears to be nothing related on the linked page, and it says last edited in 2007 (and has the [same contents](https://web.archive.org/web/20170214040753/http://wiki.c2.com/?PerlGolf) in the Wayback Machine), so it won't have changed since your post.

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 9 bytes

```
fibonacci
```

Alternate solution (21 bytes), for those disliking the built-in:

```
n->([1,1;1,0]^n)[1,2]
```

Alternate alternate solution (21 bytes):

```
n->imag(quadgen(5)^n)
```

I also posted all three solutions (in ungolfed form) to [Rosetta Code's Fibonacci page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#PARI.2FGP).

Answer (score 2):

## Reng v.2.1, 18 bytes

(Noncompeting, postdates question)

```
11{:nAo}#xxx:)+x5h
```

`11` initializes the stack with 2 `1`s. `{:nAo}#x` sets the command `x` to mean "duplicate and output as number" (`:n`) then "output a newline" (`Ao`, A = 10). Then, `xx` prints the initial 2 `1`s. `:` duplicates the TOS and `)` rotates the stack, so it becomes `b a b`. `+` adds the two figures, making it `b (a+b)`. `x` prints and leaves this new result on the stack. `5h` jumps back `5` spaces, and the loop continues.

[Try it out here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) [Or check out the github!](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Assorted-Programming-Languages/tree/master/Reng)

Answer (score 2):

## Fuzzy Octo Guacamole, 11 bytes

```
01(!aZrZo;)
```

This takes the infinite route.

Explanation:

`01` pushes `0` and then `1` to the stack.

`(` starts a infinite loop.

`!` sets the register, saving the value on the top of the stack and storing it.  It doesn't pop though.

`a` adds the 2 values.

`ZrZ` reverses the stack, pushes the register contents, and reverses again.  This pushes the stored number to the *bottom* of the stack.

`o;` peeks and prints.

`)` ends the infinite loop.

Then the whole things starts again from the `(`.

---

As a a side note, this is quite fast to hit the max long size possible in Python.  The last number it prints is `12200160415121876738`, and it repeats that forever.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 43 bytes

```
def f(n):k=9**n;return k**-~-~n/~-(k*~-k)%k
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>33</s> 32 bytes

CAUTION: This attempts to print the whole Fibonacci sequence. It does not stop.

```
a=b=1;repeat print(a<-(b=b+a)-a)
```

Pretty simple. Initialize `a` and `b`. Then a repeat loop which adds them to find the next number and print it. This loop will not stop, though eventually the overflow means it just prints `NaN` repeatedly.

Edit: saved 1 byte by switching to `a=b=1` which required a different loop control mechanism to print the first few values, and then a different assignment location, etc.

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRKE4I79cw81GVyPENkTbTVPXTfP/fwA) by using ```T``` and ```F``` as variables.

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRKE4I79cw81GN0RbI8TWTVPz/38A) by using ```T``` and ```F``` as variables, and additional inspiration from [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247838/95126)...

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, those are sufficient improvements you should submit them independently. Really like them by the way

Answer (score 2):

## Python 33 bytes

```
x,y=0,1
while 1:print x;x,y=y,x+y
```

This will be an infinite loop!

---

## Python 31 bytes

```
def f(a=[1,0]):a[:]=a[1],sum(a)
```

demonstration

```
for _ in range(10):
    f(); print f.func_defaults[0][0]

0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

Comment: The loop for your "31 char" program would need to be included in the score.

Comment: ^^ also, we usually give the count in bytes, not characters.

Comment: `+1` love the first solution! Can you explain what `f.func_defaults[0][0]` in your 2nd solution does?

Comment: @DialFrost i'm a year late, but `f.func_defaults[0]` is a reference to `a` (the first default argument of `f`), so `f.func_defaults[0][0]` gives the first item of `a`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cylon](https://github.com/tkaden4/Cylon) (Non-Competing), 12 bytes

The language is in development, Im just putting this up here.

```
1:øÌ[:ì+Á])r
```

An explanation:

```
1    ;pushes a 1 to the stack
:    ;duplicates the top of the stack
ø    ;reads a number from stdin, pushing it to the stack
Ì    ;non-pushing loop, doesn't push counter to the stack, but deletes it
[    ;start of function, to be pushed to the stack
  :  ;duplicate top of stack
  ì  ;rotate the stack, moving the copy to the back
  +  ;replaces top two objects on the stack with their sum
  Á  ;push the result to the shadowing stack (non-consuming)
]    ;end of function
)    ;switch to shadowed stack
r    ;standard library call, reverses a stack
     ;stack implicitly printed
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```rb
:++2.*
```

In J-uby, `+` on a proc (or a symbol in this case, as symbols can be used as procs in J-uby), defines a recurrence relation. It takes a starter array, and then produces a function that takes `n`, and then applies itself to the starter array `n` times, pushing the result to the end and removing the first element. Naturally `:+ + [0,1]` is a recurrence relation that starts with elements `0, 1` and adds them together `n` times.

`2.*` is shorthand for `[0,1]`

Answer (score 2):

## bc, 21

```
for(b=1;b=a+(a=b);)a
```

The trailing newline is significant.

Outputs the entire sequence.  `bc` has arbitrary precision arithmetic, so this continues forever.

Answer (score 2):

## [OIL](https://github.com/L3viathan/OIL), 46 bytes

This program writes an infinite unstoppable stream of fibonacci numbers. It is mostly copied from the standard library but fit to the requirements and golfed.

```
14
add
17
17
14
swap
17
17
4
17




11
6
0
0
1
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a cool answer, I've never heard of the language before. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein), <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 21 + 3 = 24 bytes (non-competing)

Run with the `000` topology

```
(1)\((@
):?\1-+(:(+)$
```

### Explanation

When the program starts it executes `(1)` which will put a 1 under the input.  It then deflects into the main loop.

The main loop is on the second line.  It starts with the `\` character.  Unwrapped it looks like:

```
\1-+(:(+)$):?
```

This will redirect our pointer if the counter is zero or perform one iteration of the fibonacci sequence otherwise.

Once the counter reaches zero we are deflected to the code `((@`, this will hide the top two values (the counter and one of the fibonacci numbers) and terminate the program.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n<3or f(n-2)+f(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qz8Y4v0ghTSNP10hTG0QZav4vKMrMK9HITSzQSNNRKErMS0/VMNRRMDLV1NT8DwA)

One catch: this outputs `True` instead of `1`. This is allowed by [this meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067).

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia/blob/master/codepage.md)

```
0₁@+₌ₓ
```

I might make a built-in for this in the future, but built-ins are boring anyway.

#### Explanation

```
0₁      Push 0 and 1
  @     Push an input
   +₌ₓ  Add the top two stack elements, without popping them, (input) times
        Implicitly print the top stack element.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>49</s> 40 chars

```
a,b=0,1
exec"a,b=b,b+a;"*input()
print b
```

#### Function form, 44 chars

```
def f(n):a,b=0,1;exec"a,b=b,b+a;"*n;return b
```

My take on this challenge. Didn't find this kind of an answer yet. I hope it's a valid one.

Print's n:th Fibonacci number. Functions by multiplying the string inside exec n times and then executing it as Python.

Edit: input() instead of int(raw_input())

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you don't need to the `()` around `exec` in Python 2.

Comment: @StepHen That seems to be true, thanks, down by 2 chars

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot: this would be considered a snippet because it preassumes the value of `n`. Generally you must write either a full program that gets input, or a function. So, you would have to replace `n` with `input()`. See [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/65836) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>7</s> 2 bytes

```
İf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//8iGtP//AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 39 bytes

```php
<?php for($b=1;;)echo$a=-$a+$b+=$a,' ';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0AhLb9IQyXJ1tDaWjM1OSNfJdFWVyVRWyVJ21YlUUddQd36/38A)

**Explanation**

```php
<?php
```

An infinite loop is started. The zero-th term in the series, initially `$a`, is 0, so needn't be assigned. `$b` 
is initially the second term and so is set to 1.

```php
for ($b = 1;;)
```

The part which does all the work is `echo $a = -$a + $b += $a, ' ';`. Here it is 
expanded.

```php
{
```

Calculate the new value for `$b`: the next term is the sum of the previous two.

```php
    $b = $b + $a;
```

`$a` needs to be moved on one term as well. It is calculated by subtracting itself 
from the new value of `$b`.

```php
    $a = $b - $a;
```

For byte-saving convenience, it is $a that is echoed each time—followed by a space!

```php
    echo $a, ' ';
}
```

Comment: This can be 31 bytes since you don't need PHP's opening tag (you can run with `php -r "code here"` without opening tag) and you can use `_` as separator instead of space: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFSSbA2trTVTkzPyVRJtdVUStVWStG1VEnXirf//BwA "PHP – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## C, 64 bytes

```
a,x,y,z=1;main(){for(;;){a=y;y=z;z=a;x+=y;y=x;printf("%d ",x);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9Rp0KnUqfK1tA6NzEzT0OzOi2/SMPaWrM60bbSutK2yrrKNtG6QhvMqbAuKMrMK0nTUFJNUVDSqdC0rq39/x8A) Uses the same method as my [Implicit answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142476/61563).

Comment: [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9Rp0KnUqfK1tA6NzEzT0OzGkwVFGXmlaRpKKmmKCjpVGjqVNpW6FRo24IUJgI5VTqJtpWa1rX//wMA).

Answer (score 2):

## Chip-8, 36 bytes

```
6301 'LD v3,1
6D05 'LD vD,5
6E0A 'LD vE,A
8344 'ADD v3,v4
A200 'LD I,200
F333 'LDD [I],v3
8343 'XOR v3,v4
8433 'XOR v4,v3
8343 'XOR v3,v4
F265 'LD v2,[I]
F029 'LDF I,v0
00E0 'CLS
DFF5 'DRW vF,vF,5
F129 'LDF I,v1
DDF5 'DRW vD,vF,5
F229 'LDF I,v2
DEF5 'DRW vE,vF,5
1206 'JMP 206
```

Displays Fibonacci numbers (up to 233) in decimal. (It might be shorter to use hexadecimal, but I think that's cheating)

This one writes the numbers into memory:

```
6001
A300
8014
F055
8013
8103
8013
1204
```

... but it's actually longer than valid numbers it writes:

```
01 01
02 03
05 08
0D 15
22 37
59 90
E9 79 (overflow)
```

Answer (score 2):

## VBA, 28 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and infinitely outputs the `n`-th term of the Fibonacci Sequence while iterating `n`

```vb
i=1:Do:k=i+j:i=j:j=k:?j:Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 1 [byte](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

Get the *n*th Fibonacci number:

```
Ḟ
```

Explanation:

```
           Implicit input
 Ḟ         Return (input)-th Fibonacci number
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//4Y55//8bmQIA)

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

Get an infinite list of Fibonacci numbers:

```
0`ĐḞƤ⁺ł
```

Explanation:

```
0           Push 0 [this is the counter]
 `    ł     While the counter is not zero (checked at 'ł')
  Đ         Duplicate the counter
   ḞƤ       Print the (counter)-th Fibonacci number
     ⁺      Increment the counter
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/fIOHIhIc75h1b8qhx19Gm//@NTAE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

Just to add to the collection.

0-indexed, using `0` as the first number in the sequence.

```
MgU
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=TWdV&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## R16K1S60 Assembly, 36 bytes

```
mov bx, ip
mov ax, ip
mov sp, data
jmp inner
prg:
mov cx, [sp+ax]
mov [sp+bx], cx
inner:
mov ex, [sp]
mov dx, [sp+bx]
mov [sp], dx
add ex, dx
mov [sp+ax], ex
send ax, ex
jmp prg

data:
dw 0x0000
dw 0x0001
```

Pretty simple. Abuses 7 registers, including the instruction pointer (for some predefines)

To note why I used the IP instead of a constant, it's because the R16K1S60 has to use an extra word (two bytes) to encode a constant into an instruction.

Alongside that, I used ax and bx instead of ex and dx for the offset because ex and dx cannot be referenced in only 3 bits (the size of the offset section of instructions that support it)

Outputs the number as a word on port 2

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes (was 33)

```hs
f=0:1:[f!!n+f!!(n+1)|n<-[0..]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P83WwMrQKjpNUTFPG0ho5Gkbatbk2ehGG@jpxcb@z03MzFOwVUjJ51IAgoKizLwSBRWFNAVFRQUDTCFDTCEjTCFjTCETTCFTTCGz/wA)

Comment: You should add a [TIO](https://tio.run) link and some sample cases

Comment: @MuhammadSalman They do not have to add a link. I think "should" is a bit too forceful.

Comment: Ok I added the TIO link, this is my first time posting

Comment: @mrFoobles For demonstration purposes, I think `main=print f` would be more impressive as it shows the magnitude of infinite lists.

Comment: @JonathanFrech yeah, should have been you **could** add and not **should** add

Answer (score 2):

### Prolog, <strike>36</strike> <strike>35</strike> 29 bytes

```
X+Y:-writeln(X),Z is X+Y,Y+Z.
```

Run with `1+1.`
(I don't think having to call the base case is cheating, but let me know.)

Prints the first parameter and a newline, sets Z to X+Y, then does a recursive call.

Edit 1: Can use writeln(X) instead of write(X),nl, saving one character.

Edit 2: Can use X+Y as a predicate instead of f(X,Y), saving 6 characters. Also the initial call is shorter.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! The usual consensus is to include the function invocation if it needs to be called with special arguments.

Comment: Should I include the call in the character count?

Comment: 26 bytes: `X+Y+O:-O=X;Z is X+Y,Y+Z+O.` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P0I7UtvfStffNsI6SiGzWAHI14nUjtL21/v/31DbEEhzWaNDAA "Prolog (SWI) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
lambda p,a=5**.5:round((.5+a/2)**p/a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcE7DoAgDADQ3VN0bKsRP2Ex8SYuNYqSaCEEB0@PvhfffAYdi5uXcsm9bgKxkdkyt3ZK4dENsbW1mIGYoxEqLiTw4BWS6LFj33U0VfCLyWtGh56ofA)

## Explanation

Fib(n) = Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2) with Fib(0) = Fib(1) = 1

Using some simplification, this becomes:

[image: Fibonacci Golden Ratio]

For `n > 0`, this becomes

[image: n greater than 0]

Where `round` is a function that rounds to the nearest integer.

```python
lambda p,                              # defines the anonymous function
         a=5**.5:                      # sets a to \sqrt{5}
                 round((.5+a/2)**p/a)  # Runs the function and returns the result
```

Comment: This loses precision at only `n=71`, outputting `308061521170130` instead of `308061521170129`

Answer (score 2):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), 68 bytes

```
y+_->y+a+b
y+0_->z
z+a->z+_
z+0a->x
x+b->x+a
x+0b->y+Out_a+Out_" "!y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f@/Ujte165SO1E7iatS2wDIruKq0k4EUtrxQIYBkFXBVaGdBKS0E4EMgySQav/SkvhEMKmkoKRY@f//v/yCksz8vOL/uilGAA)

Outputs the 1-based sequence infinitely, If you want 0-based (i.e. `0 1 1 2 3 5...`), you can change the trailing `y` to either `x` or `z`.

#### Explanation:

```
!y              # Initialise the program with the y flag alongside the default _

y+_->y+a+b      # Convert all _ atoms to a and b atoms
y+0_->z         # Once we're out of _ atoms, change to the z flag

z+a->z+_        # Convert the a atoms back to _ atoms
z+0a->x         # Switch to the x flag

x+b->x+a        # Convert all b atoms to a atoms
x+0b->y         # Once we're out, change to y flag
       +Out_a   # Print the number of a atoms
       +Out_" " # And a separator
```

If it makes you feel better, here's a more pseudo-codey version:

```
_=1
while true:
    a=a+_
    b=_
    _=a
    a=b
    print a
```

Answer (score 2):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle), 21 bytes

```
  1+ ~!
CB0CA~
^ 1  <
```

Outputs an unending sequence. Use the `-u` flag to get output in decimal. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/19BwVBboU6Ry9nJwNmxjitOwVBBweb//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3VLAQ)

**Note:** the current BitCycle interpreter doesn't play very well with infinite output. You have to halt the program (Ctrl-C) before it displays anything. On TIO, letting the program run until the 60-second timeout shows no output, either--you have to click the Run button (or hit Ctrl-Enter) again to halt it.

#### Explanation

This explanation assumes you're familiar with BitCycle.

Conceptually, we store two numbers at a time, the *smaller* and the *larger*. At each step, we output the larger, set the new larger to be the larger plus the smaller, and set the new smaller to be the larger.

We store and output the numbers in unary (using `1` bits), but we also need a separator (`0` bit) after each number output. Our approach is to store the separator at the end of each number. When adding two numbers, we discard the separator from the first number added, and keep the separator from the second number added.

In the code, the leftmost `C` collector holds the smaller number, while the rightmost `C` collector holds the larger. We're actually going to store everything negated, so the numbers are made of `0` bits and the separators are `1` bits. Thus, the leftmost `C` initially gets a single `1` (unary zero plus a separator bit) and the rightmost `C` gets `01` (unary one plus a separator bit).

The `C` collectors open and dump their contents straight into the `B` and `A` collectors.

Next, the `A` collector opens, holding the larger number. It goes through a couple of dupneg devices, with the following results:

- A copy goes into the leftmost `C` collector, becoming the new smaller number.
- A negated copy goes into the sink `!` and is output.
- A doubly-negated copy goes into the rightmost `C` collector, but the `+` ensures that it's only the `0` bits, not the trailing `1` separator.

Finally, the `B` collector opens and dumps its contents into the rightmost `C`, adding the former smaller number to the former larger number to create the new larger number. The cycle repeats forever.

#### Other versions

Here's a modified version (still 21 bytes) that strips the separator off the smaller number (instead of the larger) before adding:

```
10>v ~!
BA+BA~
^    <
```

And here's an **18-byte** version that starts at 0 instead of 1. (Thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) for golfing it down from 21 bytes.) Here, we start with the "smaller" number at 1 and the "larger" number at 0, generating the extended Fibonacci sequence 1,0,1,1,2,3,... (Since the "larger" number is what we output, we don't see the first 1.)

```
 1+ ~!
CBCA~
^10 <
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net), 120 bytes

Defines a class `F` with a static method `f` that calculates the nth Fibonacci number. My implementation is essentially an iterative solution that stores partially computed Fibonacci numbers on the stack.

```
.class F
.super java/io/File
.method static f(I)I
ldc 0
ldc 1
dup_x1
iadd
iinc 0 -1
iload_0
ifgt $-9
ireturn
.end method
```

## Some interesting golfing tricks used

1. Extending `java/io/File` is shorter than extending `java/lang/Object` (The super line cannot be omitted).  I've check and `File` is tied for the shortest fully qualified class name.
2. Making this an instance method would let me remove `static` from the method header but, then I would have to explicitly implement an empty constructor to make the function callable (costing quite a few bytes).
3. Juggling the Fibonacci values on the stack turned out to be shorter than storing them in local variables.
4. On the other hand it's worth storing the index in a local variable. This makes stack management easier (i.e. shorter) without too much extra length since there is an instruction for adding or subtracting from locals variables.
5. Although the JVM technically requires that you declare the maximum stack size before hand with `.limit stack 5`, this can be omitted if the class file is executed with the `-noverify` flag. I'm pretty sure this is some sort of undefined behavior but, it works in this this case.

## Test setup

To test the code you, need a main method to invoke the static method.

```
class FibTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            System.out.println(F.f(i));
        }
    }
}
```

You then need to use `jasmin.jar` (obtained from the source forge linked in the title) to build `F.class` before building and executing the test file. Since the stack size was omitted, you need to execute the class with `-noverify`. The makefile below handles this.

```
test: FibTest.class
    java -noverify FibTest

FibTest.class: FibTest.java F.class
    javac FibTest.java    

F.class: F.j
    java -jar jasmin.jar F.j
```

Answer (score 2):

## Zsh, 31 bytes

[try it online](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IQUMj0dbQOknbNtE6Uds2SVMzNTkjX0ElUUEl6f9/AA)

```zsh
for ((a=1;b+=a;a+=b))echo $a $b
```

<sub>32 bytes, based on [James Brown's awk solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180451/15940):</sub>

`for ((y=1;z=x+y;y=z))echo $[x=y]`

<sub>42 bytes, to halt before int overflow:</sub>

`(for ((a=1;b+=a;a+=b))echo $a $b)|head -46`

<sub>NB: For a properly "endless" solution I need logic for long long (..) long integers, per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3072444)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

## pure bash, 43 chars

Inspired from [user unknown's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence/1954?noredirect=1#comment456857_1954):

```
for((r=l=i=1;i++<40;l+=r+=l)){ echo $r $l;}
```

Not really golfed, but I like it anyway.

Or

```
r=1 l=0;echo {,,}{,,}{,,}\ $[r+=l]\ $[l+=r]
```

Answer (score 2):

### 8086/8088 machine code, 8 bytes

The machine code is on the left; the middle column is disassembly and the rightmost column is an explanation.

```
40      ; inc ax          set ax to 1
41      ; inc cx          set cx to 1
ef      ; out [dx], ax    output ax to port [dx] (that is, port 0)
03 c1   ; add ax, cx      set ax to ax + cx
91      ; xchg ax, cx     exchange ax with cx
eb fa   ; jmp -4          jump to "out [dx], ax"
```

Assumptions:

- The registers AX, CX and DX are initially 0.
- A number may be output by writing it as a word to port 0.

This runs forever, outputting the Fibonacci numbers modulo \$2^{16}\$ = 65,536, starting with 1, 1.

Answer (score 2):

### [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 2 bytes

Answer to the open exercise on the Oasis repo.

```
+T
```

### Explanation

Expanded program:

```
bc+10
```

When + requires 1 parameter, it tries to calculate a(n-1). For the other parameter, it tries to calculate a(n-2). (Hence the expansion.)

In addition, the T instruction expands to 10 in the program, which are the base test cases (a(0) is 0. a(1) is 1. Since base test cases are popped from the end before the Oasis program is executed in reverse.)

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/1875P///2YA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), <s>28</s> 25 bytes

```
?01
^/ 
|.#
!9]
-0
!0]
+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/397AkCtOX4GrRk@ZS9EylkvXgEvRIJZL2/D/fwA)

Outputs the Fibonacci numbers separated by tabs starting from 1. This shows off the behaviour of variables in Cascade, in that the variables `1` and `0` aren't static in this program.

Unfolded, this looks something like:

```
     @
     ^
    ^ \
   / . |
  #  9 |
  ]    |
 0 -   |
  ] 0  |
 1 +   /
  1 0 /
     |
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/XwEEHLjAVByYilOIAdH6CnoKNUCGsoKCJZgRC5IEMgwUdCEMoIgBmGGooA3SABQxBIroQwyr@f8fAA)

This initially branches twice, with the leftmost going down the tree until it sets (`[`) the variable `1` to the sum (`+`) of `1` and `0`. Then it sets `0` to that value to the result of that minus `0`. This has the effect of advancing one element in the Fibonacci sequence.For example, the values of repeated executions are:

```
0 1
1 1
1 2
2 3
3 5
5 8
8 13
...
```

Finally it prints the total result of that, which is the new value of `0`. The next branch prints the tab separator (`.9`), and the final branch loops back around to the top of the program.

Answer (score 2):

## [Taktentus](https://taktentus.herokuapp.com/), 87 bytes

```
a:=1
@wy_n:=a
@wy:=32
b:=1
n:=44
@>=n
_:=@stop
@wy_n:=a
@wy:=32
c:=a
a+=b
b:=c
n--
_-=8
```

n are variable how many times we count (n-1 because first are writing directly)

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>21</s> 17 bytes

```
0z[dp_3R+lmx]dsmx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9@gKjqlIN44SDsntyI2pTi34v9/AA)

This prints the Fibonacci sequence endlessly.

---

---

My previous (21-byte) version accepted an input \$n\$ on stdin, outputting the \$n^\text{th}\$ Fibonacci number on stdout (1-indexed):

`9k5v1+2/?^5v/.5+0k1/p`

Answer (score 2):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://github.com/bigyihsuan/International-Phonetic-Esoteric-Language), 28 bytes

```
<f>/b1ɨʌʟ|e|1zb1z<f>d<fib>s|e|\
```

A function that expects a number \$n \ge 0\$ to be on the stack, and leaves the \$n\$-th Fibonacci number.

Explanation:

```
<f>/ (n1 -- n2) (where n2 is the n1-th fibonacci number)
         (check for case n=1)
b        (dup)
 1       (push 1)
  ɨ      (n>1?)
   ʌ     (skip if n>1)
    ʟ⟨e⟩ (if n<=1, jump to end label)
1                (push 1)
 z               (subtract)
  b              (dup)
   1             (push 1)
    z            (subtract)
     <f>         (recurse)
        d        (swap)
         <f>     (recurse)
            s    (add)
             ⟨e⟩ (end label)
\
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry), 46 bytes

```
{}{<{}{<[<>{}]{{}[<><<>()>]}>}>}{{}{{}}{{}}}()
```

How to run:

```
$ target/Flurry -nin -c "{}{<{}{<[<>{}]{{}[<><<>()>]}>}>}{{}{{}}{{}}}()" 8
34
```

It doesn't use the stack at all (except for fetching the input number from the pre-populated stack). Instead, it uses pure functional construction developed [by Anders Kaseorg in my SKI golf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198842/78410).

```
one = \f. \x. f x
    = I
    = {{}}

one-pair = \f.f one one
         = {{}{{}}{{}}}

succ = \n. \f. \x. f (n f x)
     = \n. \f. S (\x. f) (n f)
     = \n. S (\f. S (K f)) n
     = S (S . K)
     = <><<>()>

next-pair-helper = \f. \m. \n. f n (m succ n)
                 = \f. \m. S f (m succ)
                 = \f. S f ∘ (\m. m succ)
                 = {<[<>{}]{{}[<><<>()>]}>}

next-pair = \p. \f. p (next-pair-helper f)
          = \p. p ∘ next-pair-helper
          = {<{}{<[<>{}]{{}[<><<>()>]}>}>}

fib = {} next-pair one-pair K
    = {}{<{}{<[<>{}]{{}[<><<>()>]}>}>}{{}{{}}{{}}}()
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [5 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

Since I finally implemented sequences in my interpreter this is now a valid submission :)

```
╔Tò”7
```

## Explained

Unpacked: `[1 1{+`

```
[ Sequence...
  1 1 ...with 2 values initialized at 1...
  { ...the rest of which are determined by the block...
    + ...that adds the top two values
  } Implied, can be removed
] Implied, can be removed
```

Since Arn supports infinite sequences and BigNums, this will continuously output fibonacci numbers infinitely (hypothetically)

Answer (score 2):

## [Barrel](https://github.com/LorenDB/barrel), 26 bytes

Disclaimer: The language is newer than the question, but I didn't even think of golfing this until after I'd created the language. I did update the language after I originally wrote the answer, and changed my answer, but that was because I was fixing the interpreter and made some changes to the spec to make the language work better. I wasn't cheating, I promise :)

```
+&1:0¤n &0:@1&1:a#@0+←1
```

Explanation:

```
+                          // set the accumulator to one by incrementing (initialization)
 &1:0                      // set register 1 to value 0 (initialization)
     ¤               ←1   // define a target that can be jumped to; then, jump to the previously defined jump target
      n                    // print the accumulator as a number and implicitly print the following space
        &0:@1              // set register 0 to register 1
             &1:a          // set register 1 to the value of the accumulator
                 #         // for as many times...
                  @0       //     ... as [value of register 0]...
                    +      //         ... increment the accumulator
```

I find it a bit hard to explain this further, so here's a rough chart of the accumulator and the two registers used during execution which will hopefully remove any confusion:

```
acc   reg[0]    reg[1] |
---------------------- |
1     <uninit>  0      | initialize; print acc("1")
1     0         1      | set reg[0] to reg[1]; set reg[1] to acc
1     0         1      | add reg[0] to acc; jump back and print acc ("1")
1     1         1      | set reg[0] to reg[1]; set reg[1] to acc
2     1         1      | add reg[0] to acc; jump back and print acc ("2")
2     1         2      | set reg[0] to reg[1]; set reg[1] to acc
3     1         2      | add reg[0] to acc; jump back and print acc ("3")
3     2         3      | set reg[0] to reg[1]; set reg[1] to acc
5     2         3      | add reg[0] to acc; jump back and print acc ("5")
5     3         5      | set reg[0] to reg[1]; set reg[1] to acc
8     3         5      | add reg[0] to acc; jump back and print acc ("8")
```

...and so forth and so on.

Comment: Added the bounty! Also, you don't need the disclaimer, there used to be a rule banning languages newer than the challenge but it was removed a while back :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pinecone](https://github.com/wmww/Pinecone), 35 bytes

```
b:0;a:1;tru@(print:a;t:a;a:a+b;b:t)
```

Competitive Pinecone answer!

Comment: How did you get to know Pinecone? For me it was because I wanted to learn how to make my own language

Comment: @ophact I was researching on creating Lexers, and I found an article on it, that's how i reached there :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 47 bytes

```
F: func[N][either N < 2[n][(F N - 2)+ F N - 1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmqIQHavw381KIa00LznaLzY6NbMkI7VIwU/BRsEoOi82WsMNyNZVMNLUVoCwDGNj/xcUZeaVAPmGXDCWEZxlDGeZ/AcA)

First red answer. Modified from the solution on [this page.](https://www.scriptol.com/programming/fibonacci.php#rebol)

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 38 bytes

```
var a,b=1
while 1>0:a=b-a;echo a;b+=a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY31coSixQSdZJsDbnKMzJzUhUM7QysEm2TdBOtU5Mz8hUSrZO0bRO5IKqhmmCaAQ)

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 64 bytes, with arbitrary precision

```
import bigints
var a,b=initBigInt(1)
while 1>0:a=b-a;echo a;b+=a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY3HTJzC_KLShSSMtMz80qKucoSixQSdZJsM_MyS5wy0z3zSjQMNbnKMzJzUhUM7QysEm2TdBOtU5Mz8hUSrZO0bRMh5kCNgxkLAA)

Thanks to @JoKing  and @cairdcoinheringaahing

Comment: Can you golf `true` to `1` and `temp` to `c`?

Comment: You can also golf the declaration to `var a,b=1` if you then change the update section to `a=b-a;echo a;b+=a`. You can also update the `true` part to be `1>0` like in your arbitrary precision code

Comment: Right thanks, stupid of me to leave it like that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 126 bytes

Neither short nor pretty, but possibly a new method!

```python
from decimal import*
def f(n):l=n//4+1;p=10**l;getcontext().prec=n*l-l+1;return int(str(Decimal(p**2)/Decimal(p**2-p-1))[-l:])
```

Uses, for example:

`1/(1000000-1000-1) = 0.000 001 001 002 003 005 008 013 021 034 055 089 ...`

`l` can be any upper bound for the number of digits of the Fibonacci number after the one we want.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BCoMwEETvfkWO2dTUxPZQFG/9C/EgGlshbpZtCu3Xp4pQSg8zMPBmGHrHe8DThTilicMiRjfMS@/FvFDgqLLRTWKSCJVvsCjOB1tTY41Svr65OASM7hUlHInd0KDy2q8Eu/hkFDNG@Ygsr/ukJKVKKH6TJm0BWu2rDtIUWGwlwT3enLR5aaDKBPG2g/l2ArIv1Fpj8lW7me6fTB8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Grok](https://github.com/AMiller42/Grok-Language), 16 bytes

```
1z1j
wYZlYp2yp+9
```

[Try it Online!](http://grok.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=1z1j%0AwYZlYp2yp%2B9&inputs=)

Prints an infinite, tab-separated sequence. (Tabs instead of spaces/newlines since they are golfier.) The `5` flag is just so it times out faster.

Explanation:

```
1z           # Print the initial 1
  1          # Push 1 to the stack
   j         # Start the IP moving down
   l         # Start the IP moving right
    Yp       # Get the last number on the stack
      2yp    # Get the number before that (initially 0)
         +   # Add them together
w         9  # Print a Tab
 YZ          # Print the next number without popping it
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/),  <s>40</s> 36 bytes

Prints the infinite Fibonacci sequence. Saved 4 bytes by using a goto operator instead of a while loop.

```lua
i,j=0,1::a::j,i=i,i+j print(i)goto a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/UyfL1kDH0Moq0coqSyfTNlMnUztLoaAoM69EI1MzPb8kXwGoCgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), 262 bytes

```
HAI 1
I HAS A x
GIMMEH x
x IS NOW A NUMBR
BOTH SAEM x 0
O RLY?
YA RLY
VISIBLE "0"
NO WAI
I HAS A a ITZ 0
I HAS A b ITZ 1
I HAS A c ITZ 0
IM IN YR l UPPIN YR i WILE BOTH SAEM i SMALLR OF i DIFF OF x 2
c R SUM OF a b
a R b
b R c
IM OUTTA YR l
VISIBLE b
OIC
KTHXBYE
```

Reads `n` from STDIN and returrns the `n`th Fibonacci number.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BDoIwEEX3c4ofTiBcwBQFO5FS0xYRd7S6ICFhy@2xYNDNzP8zmfdnnMYwvd7LIgUjJYYUFgIzXVipQkYxgy1q3cZp3ajcUK6dhBWFwowDaZiqO1In1k53tpxXBZJDQrVGK/iH7MHuGQ927zf/jwz7XoFrdAYjmtvtKwe0HKn/5AFWiaoy0GXUZy7LVc3IKMDANmq1PTz10XrysYaVrBvnxAb/vepJ84muTj7yrliWNPsA)

Answer (score 2):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle) `-u`, <s>67</s> 45 bytes

```
v1<   <
BvC1Av
v~~v <
>  Cv>^
   v~~
  \>101!
```

[Try it online!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/BitCycle/?p=s1wc3wrBsC1Asrsz2scwrec2Csenrc3sz2rc2ie101b&f=1)

It's beautiful... I have some idea of how this works.

The `A`, `B` and `C` are collectors. when the field is empty, the first non-empty collector (sorting in alphabetical order) has all collectors opened.

The basic idea is that the two numbers are stored in the `B` and `A` collectors. On each iteration:

- The bits stored in A are emitted into the main C collector
- The bits stored in B are duplicated and sent to the main C collector, and the C collector next to the A collector. This is necessary because otherwise the `A` collector would open before the `C` collector.
- Both `C` collectors open. One emits its bits into A (previously stored in B).
- The other duplicates its bits, and sends one stream to the B collector and the other stream to an output device
- Duplicating bits also emits negated bits. *one* of these (a 0) from the B collector is sent to the output device via the `\`

This is because integer outputt in BitCycle is done in unary, with a sequence of n 1s and then a 0. a 0 must be sent before the next iteration begins.

The `101` is initially emitted to the output device to print 1, 1 (the 0 to print the next 1 is supplied before the 2 is emitted).

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `benchmark.fib3`, 3 bytes

```
fib
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQlJqXnJGbWJStl5aZZKxQUJRaUlJZUJSZV6JgzcVl@h8o@l/vPwA)

And a non- built-in version:

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 32 bytes

```factor
[ 0 1 rot [ tuck + ] times nip ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE7CoAwEAXA3lO8XhAtbPQAYmMjVmIRwoaEfFk3haePM0Zpydyucz@2BZ44UcBrqzGBEJVYFCaRr7BLgrXr5nZjxATOghtStUePB@IivUiu4GlahYCh/Q)

Answer (score 2):

## [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.org/calculator), 38 bytes

```
n
InputBox(n
Iteration(p+q,p,q,{0,1},n
```

Input in Input Box. Outputs the nth term of the 0-indexed Fibonacci sequence starting at \$F_0=0\$, \$F_1=1\$.

[Try It On GeoGebra!](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/mtkpy32b)

Answer (score 2):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), 19 bytes

```
(($3!x)($1)!){$~1}x
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdcGCpaUlaboWmzU0VIwVKzQ1VAw1FTWrVeoMaysgMlAFy6KVDA2VYqE8AA)

The input \$n\$ is zero-indexed, taken as a command-line argument in decimal. The output is in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length is the \$n\$th Fibonacci number.

```
(           # Capture group $1 - unset on the first iteration, and on each
            # subsequent, contains the previous iteration's match.
    ($3!x)  # On the second iteration, match a single "x", seeding the Fibonacci
            # sequence. On subsequent iterations, match $3.
    ($1)    # Copy $1 into capture group $3, and also match it.
!           # Try the below only when the above cannot match.
            # Zero-width match - executed only on the first iteration, seeding
            # the Fibonacci sequence.
){$~1}      # Iterate the number of times passed as command-line argument #1.
x           # Match a single "x", representing the 0th Fibonacci number.
```

This works similarly to [Martin Ender's Fibonacci-matching regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126373/am-i-a-fibonacci-number/126405#126405), but it is freed from one of its limitations. To illustrate, a straight port of that regex would have been the following 23 byte Regenerate program (shown alongside this 19 byte one):

```
(($3!)($1)!x){$~1-1}x!x
(($3!x)($1)!){$~1}x
```

Martin Ender's regex has to work around the fact that any loop with an indefinite maximum iteration count will exit after making a zero-width match. But unlike a regex that must *match* any arbitrary Fibonacci number, for this problem we *generate* one from a known index, giving us a definite iteration count. Thus our first iteration can make a zero-width match.

A straight port of Martin Ender's regex to Regenerate is 4 bytes longer, because it's naturally "-1 indexed" rather than 0 or 1 indexed. So it needs `{$~1-1}` to fix the indexing; that in turn forces the need for a `!x` alternative at the end, because a negative number of loop iterations causes a non-match. If keeping it "-1 indexed", the two would be identical in length:

```
(($3!)($1)!x){$~1}x  # -1 indexed: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...
(($3!x)($1)!){$~1}x  #  0 indexed: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5,  8, ...
```

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), 30 bytes (26 characters)

```
((($4!‍)($2)!){$~1}‍)${#1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdcGCpaUlaboW-zQ0NFRMFB819GpqqBhpKmpWq9QZ1oK4KtXKhrUQRVC1y6KVDA2VYqE8AA)

The output is in decimal. This is achieved by outputting the Fibonacci number in unary invisibly, using a string of Zero-Width Joiner (U+200D) characters instead of `x`, before outputting the length of that string in decimal using `${#1}` (measured using by wrapping the entire unary regex in capture group `$1`, thus incrementing the previous capture group numbers).

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-n`, 5 bytes

```
Jᵐ#3<
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJunlLsgqWlJWm6Fsu9Hm6doGxss6Q4KbkYKrZgswGXIZcRlzGXCZcplxmXOZcFlyVECgA)

```
Jᵐ#3<
J       Non-deterministically split the range [0,input) into parts
 ᵐ#     Take the length of each part
   3<   Check if all lengths are less than 3
```

The flag `-n` set the interpreter to `CountValues` mode, which counts the number of possible results.

---

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-n`, 6 bytes

```
ʷ{←Pᶜ←
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJunlLsgqWlJWm6FmtPba9-1DYh4OG2OUBqSXFScjFUZsFmAy5DLiMuYy4TLlMuMy5zLgsuS4gUAA)

The flag `-n` set the interpreter to `CountValues` mode, which counts the number of possible results.

It takes an integer as input, and prints the Fibonacci number at that position.

```
ʷ{←Pᶜ←
ʷ       Repeat the following function until it fails.
 {      Start a block.
  ←     Decrement the top of the stack.
   P    Check if the top of the stack is positive. If it is, keep the element unchanged. If it is not, fail.
    ᶜ   Optionally apply the following function.
     ←  Decrement the top of the stack.
```

---

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 7 bytes

```
1:ᶦ{$ᵉ+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FqsNrR5uW1at8nBrp_aS4qTkYqg4TB4A)

This takes no input and prints all the Fibonacci numbers.

```
1:ᶦ{$ᵉ+
1       Push 1 onto the stack.
 :      Duplicate the top of the stack.
  ᶦ     Iterate the following function zero or more times non-deterministically.
   {    Start a block.
    $   Swap the top two elements of the stack.
     ᵉ  Apply the following function, and then push the original top of the stack onto the stack.
      + Add the top two elements of the stack.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle/), 14 bytes

```
.'L1pj2'.S#1+|
```

Goes on forever in theory, but in practice it runs into the integer limit pretty quickly and spews garbage data.

You can try it on [the online interpreter](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/#.%27L1pj2%27.S%231%2B%7C), but be ready to hit "stop program".

Unfolds to this:

```
    .
   ' L
  1 p j
 2 ' . S
# 1 + | .
```

Basically does this:

```swift
var x = 1, y = 1
while true {
    print(x)
    (x, y) = (y, x + y)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [ForWhile](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ForWhile), 11 bytes

`{1'[';+:).}`

takes number `n` on stack as input, returns `n`th Fibonacci number

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=forwhile&src=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)

### Explanation

```
{         }  \ anonymous procedure
 1'          \ push 1 below argument
   [   :)    \ repeat n times
    '        \ swap the top two values on the stack  (A B -> B A)
     ;       \ copy the lower value above the higher value (B A -> B A B)
      +      \ add the op two stack elements  (B A B-> B A+B)
         .   \ discard the top stack element (only return one Fibonacci number)
```

Answer (score 2):

## ELF executable (x64), 194 bytes

*This is my first non-trivial assembly program, so there may be still room for improvement*

hexdump:

```
457f 464c 0102 0301 0000 0000 0000 0000
0002 003e 0001 0000 0078 0040 0000 0000
0040 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0040 0038 0001 0040 0000 0000
0001 0000 0007 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0040 0000 0000 0000 0040 0000 0000
00c2 0000 0000 0000 0142 0000 0000 0000
1000 0000 0000 0000 ff48 50c0 e853 0007
0000 5b58 0148 ebd8 48f2 c6c7 0141 0040
3148 b3db 880a b21e 4001 d788 3148 48d2
f3f7 8640 40d7 c780 4830 ceff 8840 fe3e
48c2 f883 7500 40e2 01b7 3148 b0c0 0f01
c305
```

*prints decimal representation of Fibonacci-numbers (truncated to last 64 bits) indefinitely*

assembly code (fasm):

```
format ELF64 executable 3
segment readable writable executable

_start:
  inc rax
                  ; rbx is initialized to zero
.loop:
  push rax
  push rbx
  call print
  pop rax         ; old value for b
  pop rbx         ; old value for a
  add rax,rbx     ; (a,b) -> (b+a,a)
  jmp .loop       ; loop infinitely

print:
  mov rsi,buffer_end          ; point to end of buffer
  xor rbx,rbx
  mov bl,10                   ; store 10 in rbx
  mov [rsi],bl                ; append new-line
  mov dl,1                    ; length
.loop:
  mov dil,dl                  ; more counter to rdi
  xor rdx,rdx                 ; clear rdx
  div rbx                     ; divmod: quotient -> rax remainder -> rdx
  xchg dl,dil                 ; move remainder to rdi (and length to rdx)
  add dil,48
  dec rsi                     
  mov [rsi],dil               ; *buffer=n%10
  inc dl                      ; length++
  cmp rax,0
  jne .loop                   ; go back to loop if rax if not zero
  mov   dil,1                   ; stdout
  xor rax,rax
  mov   al,1                      ; sys_write
  syscall
  ret

print_buffer rb 128
buffer_end = $-1
```

Answer (score 1):

### Bash 100

This is a very slow, but hey no performance penalty. First line needed.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 -lt 2 ]; then
echo $1; exit; fi
expr `$0 \`expr $1 - 1\`` + `$0 \`expr $1 - 2\``
```

Comment: More a question: You don't need a shebang, do you? See ruby, python and xy-script.

Comment: `(($1<2))&& echo $1 && exit;v=$1;p=$0;echo $(($($p $((v-1)))+$($p $((v-2)))))` 77 chars with the same approach, just different syntax and a bit faster

Comment: I see the white space surrounding the brackets and instinctively click the "comment" button to tell you it should be removed... then I remember this is bash

Comment: There is redundant whitespace here, after each semicolon.

Comment: solution fails on TIO.run , and so does the version in comments.

Answer (score 1):

### Scala, 52 chars:

```
def f(a:Int,b:Int):Int={println(a);f(b,a+b)};f(0,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

**CHIP 8**

Not so short but displays the fibonacci sequence on screen:

```
00E06600690060006101221E3900120E8200801081206F00810489F0120A6500830064F083428336833683368336F32900E0D56575088300640F8342F329D56500EE
```

without displaying on screen:

```
00E06000610182008010812081041206
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python (56 chars)

```
n=input()
x=5**0.5
print ((1+x)**n-(1-x)**n)/((2**n)*x)
```

And for the sequence

```
n=input()
i=1
x=5**0.5
while i<=n:
    print ((1+x)**i-(1-x)**i)/((2**i)*x)
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Clojure: 38 chars**

```
    (def f(lazy-cat[0 1](map +(rest f)f)))
```

run with:

```
    f
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript - 48 chars

```
for(i=1;i<n;i++){f[i]=f[i-1]+(f[i-2]?f[i-2]:0);}
```

Clean and simple... probably not a shortness winner :D

Here is the full implementation:

```
function a(n) {
    var i;
    var f = new Array();
    f[0]=1;

    for(i=1;i<n;i++){f[i]=f[i-1]+(f[i-2]?f[i-2]:0);}

    console.log(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#: <strike>83</strike> <strike>69</strike> <strike>68</strike> <strike>66</strike> <strike>58</strike> <strike>53</strike> 51

I used a nasty trinary and recursive lambda expression to achieve this one.

[Source: StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079164/c-recursive-functions-with-lambdas)

```cs
Func<ulong,ulong> f=null;f=x=>x<2?x:f(x-2)+f(x-1);
```

Usage:

```cs
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Recursive lambda expression...
        Func<ulong, ulong> f = null;
        f = x => (x < 2) ? x : f(x - 2) + f(x - 1);

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a whole number to obtain the Fibonacci sequence number for:");
        string value = Console.ReadLine();

        long numValue;
        if(UInt64.TryParse(value, out numValue))
            Console.WriteLine(f(numValue));

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end the program.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You don't have no support negative indices. Also, the "ternary" conditional operator isn't nasty if you use it right. :-)

Comment: That helps, thanks!  I don't consider ternaries nasty usually, but in a case like the one I've posted, I would do everything in my power to avoid that getting into a codebase.  It gets points for clever/short, but not readable.

Comment: lol - I posted mine without ever seeing yours. Funny to see that they're almost identical. :)

Comment: Yeah, but trying to calculate anything above `f(45)` will cause either a StackOverflow, or just take forever and some time to calculate.

Comment: I don't think you need the parentheses around `(n<2)`

Comment: Good catch!  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

### C, 45 (37)

Only because it's easy:

```
f(n){return n<2?n?1:0:f(n-1)+f(n-2);}
```

Or the more compiler-friendly/standards-compliant but more verbose version:

```
#define m main(n
m){return n<2?n?1:0:m-1)+m-2);}
```

note: once compiled, you have to call main() with an actual value (which will likely take some command line fiddling depending on OS)

Comment: Doesn't run for me.

Comment: It only runs as a stand-alone in some environments with very specific settings. I'll add a friendlier version though.

Comment: Number of arguments could work. Intresting way to pass the parameter.

Comment: `n?1:0` can be replaced with just `n`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Befunge, <s>15</s> 13 characters

```
1:.:00p+00g\#
```

I didn't spot any Befunge solutions, so I thought I'd write one.  Too bad Befunge doesn't have a rotate-n operation<s>, and trampoline `#` doesn't work at end-of-line to skip first character after looping around</s>.  Turns out that part of the spec is considered ambiguous on that point, and my initial interpretation is actually valid.

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge 98, 10 characters

```
1:"]"y+#
```

8-character code generating the fibonacci sequence on the stack, under the assumption that `#` should first wrap around then skip, which sadly does not hold in CCBI (where I run my Befunge code). It would work if we restricted the fungespace X dimension to 8 cells.

```
1#;:"]"y+;
```

Using 10 characters, the code actually works in CCBI, generating the sequence on the stack.

```
1#;:.:"]"y+;
```

With 12 characters, we have working code that outputs space-delimited numbers to stdout (would be 10 chars if based on the first version).

```
1#;:.:"]"y+:0`2*k#@;
```

This 20-character version ends the loop as soon as overflow occurs (on 32bit system, it delivers the sequence up to 1836311903). If you add 2 more characters, each number is on a separate line (insert `a,` after `:.`)

All these versions operate purely on the stack, no modification of fungespace cells. The 'printing' versions do so *in addition* to generating the sequence on the stack.

### Breakdown:

1. `1` pushes 1 on the empty stack.
2. `#` skips the next fungespace cell (`;`).
3. `:.` duplicates, pops and prints the top-of-stack value (1 in the first iteration). Inserting `a,` here outputs an ASCII 10 character, which makes a new line.
4. `:` duplicates again. (Stack now [1 1])
5. `"]"` pushes 93 (ASCII). This is explained further below. (Stack now [1 1 93])
6. `y` pops a value and pushes system information for it. In our case, that's the third-of-top value on the stack. In the first iteration, this is 0, as there are only two elements there. (Stack now [1 1 0])
7. `+` pops two values and pushes their sum. (Stack now [1 1])
8. `:0'` compares the TOS value with 0 and pushes 1 if it was greater, else 0. (It should be a backtick.) (Stack now [1 1 1])
9. `2*k#` pops and doubles our comparison result, and performs the `#` that many times (0 or 2). While the numbers are positive, it skips to the `;`, otherwise to the `@` (because `k` automatically moves the IP beyond its target with a 0 argument). (Stack now [1 1])
10. `@` terminates the program. It is only reached when overflow occurred.
11. `;` creates kind of a wormhole. It skips everything until it encounters another `;`, which it will at the third character of the line. Execution continues with step 3.)

In step 5.), I use 93 as an argument to `y`. This value is individual, because `y` outputs things like the command line arguments and environment variables, and starts returning values from the stack (top-down) if its argument is greater than the size of actual system information `y` emits. If eg. you rename the script to a different length name, you have to adjust this value.

To find the correct value, you can insert `01-y` (which pushes ALL system information) at the beginning, start in the debugger (-t switch for CCBI), step 4, see how big your stack is, add 3, and replace `]` with the resulting character.

Note that the use of `y` may cause CCBI to report an Access violation on `@` which can be safely ignored, as is the case on my system (Win8.1/64, ccbi.exe/32). The short versions keep on looping into eternity (given infinite memory).

PS: If we move the `:.` between the `y` and `+`, the printed sequence becomes *0* 1 1 2 ...
If we want it starting with 0 on the stack, we simply insert `0` at the beginning (and leave `:.` where it is now).

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC - 18 symbols

to print fibonacci sequence starting from 0:

```
;i
;While 1
;Disp real(Ans
;real(Ans)+imag(Ans)+ireal(Ans
;End
```

to print fibonacci sequence starting from 1:

```
;1
;While 1
;Disp real(Ans
;real(Ans)+imag(Ans)+ireal(Ans
;End
```

Comment: `real(Ans)-conj(iAns` is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 27

What, no Ruby answers?

```
p a=b=1;loop{a,b=(p b),a+b}
```

Prints each number, starting correctly with the first two `1`s, to STDOUT ad infinitum (VERY QUICKLY from `irb` in my environment - you've been warned). I've been learning Ruby lately, so I figured I'd contribute this. If it can be shortened in any way, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

## Element, 12 (option two) or 11 (option one)

I've decided to go back in time and answer some classic golfing questions with Element to give it some more street cred.

The following code prints out the Fibonacci sequence continuously (it overflows rather quickly).  Each number is printed separately, although there is no whitespace separation.

```
1!{4:`~2@+}
1            push 1 onto the stack
 !           flip the empty control stack to 1 to enable looping
  {       }  infinite while loop
  {4:     }  have 4 copies (3 additional) of the newest number on the stack
  {  `    }  output one copy
  {   ~   }  A fancy way to get zero from a copyusing the variable retrieval function
  {    2~ }  Move one copy from position 0 to position 2 (behind the old number)
  {      +}  add the number to the old number
```

The following code inputs a number and outputs the Nth number in the sequence (0-indexed).

```
1_'[3:~2@+]`
1             push a 1
 _'           take input then move it to the control stack
   [      ]   FOR loop
   [3:    ]   make two additional copies of the top number (3 is the total count)
   [  ~   ]   turn one copy into a zero
   [   2@ ]   move from position 0 to position 2, behind the old number
   [     +]   add the old and newer number
           `  output the result
```

For completion's sake, here is a [link to the interpreter](https://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element/blob/master/Interpreter).

Answer (score 1):

## Julia - 20 Characters

```
f=n->([1 1;1 0]^n)[]
```

I used the same basic algorithm as the Octave answer. This starts with `f(0)->1`, `f(1)->1`, to avoid needing an explicit array index. This is 4 characters shorter than the naive recursive algorithm.

```
f=n->n<2?1:f(n-1)+f(n-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <strike>39</strike> 38 bytes

```
a=1
b=1
while 1:c=a+b;print(c);a=c;b=c
```

Ungolfed:

```
a = 1
b = 1
while 1:
    c = a + b
    print(c)
    a = c
    b = c
```

Is there some way of getting rid of the `b=c` statement?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Does `a=b=c` work in Python? (Same for `a=b=1`.) Also, do you really need the space after `:`?

Comment: @MartinBüttner It did print the Fibonnaci sequence, and it also showed a weird wavy "animation" :P

Comment: @MartinBüttner Assignments can be chained, just like comparisons, but they don't return a value so you can't do `a=1+(b=c)`.

Comment: This doesn't print the right sequence. [It's not hard to fix though.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E2ydaQqzwjMydVwdCqoCgzr0QjUdM62TZRO8kaKGmdZJv8/z8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 44 bytes

```
fn f(n:u8)->u8{if n<2{n}else{f(n-1)+f(n-2)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Forth, 27 bytes

Prints them forever (until it exceeds the maximum integer).

```
: f over . 2dup + recurse ;
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/forth-gforth#@2@lkKaQX5ZapKCnYJRSWqCgrVCUmlxaVJyqYP3fQMFQIe0/AA)

Returns the *n*th Fibonacci number. This assumes I can leave garbage on the stack (the result is still on top), 30 bytes:

```
: f 1 0 rot 0 DO 2dup + LOOP ;
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/forth-gforth#@2@lkKZgqGCgUJRfAiRd/BWMUkoLFLQVfPz9AxSs/5sDpfX@AwA)

Answer (score 1):

### dc, 29 chars

```
1ddppsa[+sblalbsalbplxx]sxlxx
```

Comment: [Verified](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98wJaWgoDgxWrs4KScxJ6kYiAtyKipiiyuA5P//AA). how the $^*# does that work??

Answer (score 1):

## Vitsy, 11 Bytes

I'm *certain* there's a way to shorten these.

Print out all fibonacci (to Integer.MAX_VALUE)

```
01[D}+DNaO]
01          Push 0 and 1 to the stack.
  [       ] Repeat infinitely.
   D        Duplicate the top item of the stack.
    }       Rotate the stack to right.
     +      Add the top two items.
      D     Duplicate the top item.
       N    Print the top item out as a number.
        aO  Print a return.
```

Print out to input fibonacci (13 bytes):

```
01}\[D}+DNaO]
01            Push 0 and 1 to the stack.
  }\[       ] Get the input and repeat that many times.
     D        Duplicate the top item of the stack.
      }       Rotate the stack to right.
       +      Add the top two items.
        D     Duplicate the top item.
         N    Print the top item out as a number.
          aO  Print a return.
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Minkolang 0.10](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 10 bytes

This language was created after this challenge but not *for* it.

Stream ([link](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=01d1R%2BdN2%40), do **not** click "Run"):

```
01d1R+dN2@
```

A mite clever, if I do think so. The `2@` at the end is a 2-trampoline that jumps over the `01` at the beginning, allowing the sequence to rise unabated.

Nth Fibonacci ([link](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=01nd2%26N%2E%5Bd1R%2B%5DrN.&input=3)):

```
01nd,7&[d1R+]rN.
```

Worse than I expected, **16 bytes**. `01` sets it up, `nd,7&...N.` prints out `0` if the input is `0` and does the loop otherwise. `[d1R+]` builds up the sequence, then `r` reverses the stack and the correct number is outputted and the program ends with `N.`.

Comment: Grar! Again? You beat me by one _again_. _grumble_

Comment: .... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

(The language is newer than the question.)

```
W1o:y+YPo
```

Outputs infinite Fibonacci numbers on separate lines, beginning with 1. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/3DDfqlI7MiD//38A)

#### Explanation

The easy part is `W1`, which uses 1 as an always-truthy condition to create an infinite while loop.

We use two built-in variables, `o` and `y`, which are initially `1` and `""`, respectively. Note that an empty string in arithmetic contexts is treated as 0. At each iteration, `y` will hold the smaller of two consecutive Fibonacci numbers, and `o` will hold the larger.

The loop body is a single expression: `o:y+YPo`. It's important to know that Pip evaluates a binary-operator expression by first evaluating the left operand, then the right operand, then performing the operation. So, using the third iteration as an example (`y` is `1`, `o` is `2`):

- The left operand of `:` (the assignment operator) is `o`; we'll compute `y+YPo` and then assign that value to `o`.
- The left operand of `+` is `y`, which is currently `1`.
- The right operand of `+` is `YPo`. `YP` is a unary operator that takes the value of its operand--here, `o`, which is `2`--prints it, and yanks it into `y`. So when `YPo` is evaluated, `2` is printed, `y` is set to `2`, and the expression evaluates to `2`.
- `+` adds `1` and `2` and gives `3`.
- `:` assigns `3` to `o`.

The end result is that `2` is printed, `y` becomes `2`, and `o` becomes `3`. Repeat ad infinitum.

Answer (score 1):

## Turing machine code, 389

I wrote this the other day and decided to post it. Generates an infinite Fibonacci sequence in unary on the tape. See a commented version in action [here](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?457a5b151bb1e8cc7e14).

```
0 _ 1 r 1
1 _ _ r 2
2 _ 0 r 3
3 _ _ r 4
4 _ 0 l 5
5 0 * l 5
5 _ * l 5
5 1 * r f
a 0 1 r b
b 0 * r b
b _ * r c
c 0 * r c
c _ * r d
d _ 0 l e
e 0 * l e
e _ * l e
e 1 * r f
f 0 1 r g
f _ * r k
g 0 * r g
g _ * r h
h 0 * r h
h _ * r i
i 0 * r i
i _ 0 l j
j 0 * l j
j _ * l j
j 1 * r f
k 0 1 r l
k _ * l R
l 0 * r l
l _ * r m
m 0 * r m
m _ 0 l n
n 0 * l n
n _ * l n
n 1 * r k
R _ * r a
R 1 0 l R
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ShapeScript](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/ShapeScript), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
_1@0@'@1?+'*!#
```

This reads an integer **n** (in unary) from STDIN and prints the **n**<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number.

[Try it online!](http://shapescript.tryitonline.net/#code=XzFAMEAnQDE_KycqISM=&input=MTExMTE=)

#### How it works

```
        Input: a string of n 1's 
_       Get the length of the input to push n.
1@      Swap it with 1 (F[-1]).
0@      Swap it with 0 (F[0]).
        STACK: F[-1]   F[0]   n
'       Push a string that, when evaluated for the i-th time,
        does the following:
  @       Swap F[i-2] on top of F[i-1].
  1?      Push a copy of F[i-1].
  +       Add the copy of F[i+1] to F[i].
'       STACK: F[i-1]   F[i]
*!      Repeat the string n times and evaluate it.
#       Discard F[n] from the stack.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Binary-Encoded Golfical, 27+1 (`-x` flag)=28 bytes

Noncompeting, language postdates the question.

Hexdump:

```
00 90 02 00 01 14 0C 01 14 00 00 14 1B 1E 08 01
14 2C 17 0A 01 3A 0C 01 2D 1C 1D
```

This encoding can be converted back to the original image using the github repo's included Encoder utility (`java Encoder d "<encoded file>" "<target file>"`) or run directly by adding the `-x` flag

Original image:

[image]

Magnified 50x:

[image]

Rough translation:

```
*p=1;
*(p+1)=*p;
*p=0;
while true:
 p++;
 push *p;
 p--;
 *(p+1)=*p;
 *p=pop;
 *p+=*(p+1);
 print *p;
end while;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [beeswax](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beeswax), 12 bytes (sequence), 42 bytes (n-th Fib.)

Beeswax is newer than the question, so no competition here.

Fibonacci sequence.

```
p{N<P{*
>~+d
```

No promotion to higher bit widths implemented in my solution, so 64-bit overflow starts at the 93rd or 92nd Fibonacci number, depending if you start counting your sequence at 0 or 1:

```
0  
1  
1  
2  
3  
5  
8  
13 
21 
34 
55 
89 
.
.
.
4660046610375530309
7540113804746346429
12200160415121876738   ← 93rd Fibonacci number
1293530146158671551    ← 1st. 64-bit overflow/wraparound
13493690561280548289
```

N-th Fibonacci number:

```
;{#'<>~P~L#MM@>+@'p@{;
  _TNX~P~K#{; d~@M<
```

The same limit applies to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>224</s> <s>229</s> **227** chars

#### ...prints the `n`'th fibonacci or 2^`n`

### Golfed up:

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
typedef unsigned long long f;f main(int c,char*v[]){f n=strtoull(v[1],(char**)v[2],10)-1;f x=(c>2&&++n==0)?0:1;f y=0;while(n--!=0&&x+y>=x&&x>0){f z=x;c>2?x+=y=z:(x+=y,y=z);}printf("%llu\n",x);}
```

### Readable:

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
typedef unsigned long long f;
f main(int c,char*v[]){
    f n=strtoull(v[1],(char**)v[2],10)-1;
    f x=(c>2&&++n==0)?0:1;
    f y=0;
    while(n--!=0&&x+y>=x&&x>0){
        f z=x;
        c>2?x+=y=z:(x+=y,y=z);
    }
    printf("%llu\n",x);
}
```

If the number exceeds the length of an `unsigned long long` it will print the highest it can get.
Return type is `f` (unsigned long long) for short code, it does generate 2 compiler warnings and a note but it still compiles!

It also has the option to calculate 2^n because it initially printed that.

**Usage:**

- `./fibbin 42` - prints `42`'th fibonacci number (267914296)
- `./fibbin 42 anyInputHere` - prints 2^`n` (4398046511104).

**Don't** enter values of 0, higher than 93 (fibonacci) or higher than 63 (2^n).

**Examples:**

- `./fibbin 1` = `1`
- `./fibbin 2` = `1`
- `./fibbin 3` = `2`
- `./fibbin 4` = `3`
- `./fibbin 42` = `267914296`
- `./fibbin 92` = `7540113804746346429`
- `./fibbin 93` = `12200160415121876738` - this is the highest i can go
- `./fibbin 94` = should be 19740274219868223167, but it doesn't fit into an unsigned long long so i will print #93
- `./fibbin 1 bin` - `2`
- `./fibbin 2 bin` - `4`
- `./fibbin 3 bin` - `8`
- `./fibbin 4 bin` - `16`
- `./fibbin 42 bin` - `4398046511104`
- `./fibbin 62 bin` - `4611686018427387904`
- `./fibbin 63 bin` - `9223372036854775808` - this is the highest i can go
- `./fibbin 64 bin` - should be 18446744073709551616, but it doesn't fit into an unsigned long long so i will print 0

These tests match the output of [wolfram-alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fibonacci+1+and+fibonacci+2+and+fibonacci+3+and+fibonacci+4+and+fibonacci+42+and+fibonacci+92+and+fibonacci+93+and+2%5e1+and+2%5e2+and+2%5e3+and+2%5e4+and+2%5e42+and+2%5e62+and+2%5e63&incParTime=true), due to the heavy calculations wolfram may time out but it generally doesn't.

Comment: I'm no C expert but I think `n--!=0&&...` can be replaced with `n--&&...`

Comment: [117 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcRLCsIwEADQq0jBktgGbVfqkHoQPxCmNgbiVPpjgnh1x4Vv8dB4RBGCmcbg6d6uYk/@H5cJni6QwnLR@HDDZrPAm6yb@qCWc3XVpt4idP2g2FZAxuQ5F6mxDMmySZoLi0194mOC1xBo6lS2jnG@UFayho@IVDupb/TFLjo/ihmn1uL@8AM)

Answer (score 1):

## R - 39

Shortest - recursive, until SO:

```
f=function(i,j){cat(i);f(j,i+j)};f(1,1)
```

Until n:

```
i=j=1;for(x in 1:n){print(i);k=i;i=i+j;j=k}
```

or (a bit vectorized):

```
a=c(1,1);for(x in 1:n)print((a=c(a[2],sum(a)))[1])
```

or (without any loop or recursion):

```
a=c(1,1);sapply(1:n,function(i)a<<-c(a[2],sum(a)))[1,]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Brainf*ck, <s>489</s> 466 characters

Granted, this is a bit overkill, not to mention that it could be optimised a lot. I will get to improving it tomorrow, since it's too late today.

EDIT: Improved by a few bytes by putting stuff closer together on the tape.

```
++++++>++++++++++>+>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<[->>[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>
>>-]<<+>[<->[>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]+++++
+++[<++++++>-]>[<<+>>-]>[<<+>>-]<<]>]<[->>++++++++[<++++++>-]]<[
.[-]<]>>>>>>>>[->+<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>]>[-<+>]<<<<<<<<<<<.>>>>>>
>>>>[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<<+>[<->[>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-
<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]++++++++[<++++++>-]>[<<+>>-]>[<<+>>-]<<]>]<[-
>>++++++++[<++++++>-]]<[.[-]<]<<<<<<<<<<[->+>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>
[-<+>]<<.<]
```

(With added newlines for readability)

Answer (score 1):

## [PlatyPar](https://github.com/cyoce/PlatyPar), 7 bytes

```
0A1wAC+
```

[Try it online](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/ParStack/master/page.html?code=0A1wAC+)!

Explanation:

```
0A1       ## push first two Fibonacci numbers to stack and print them
    w     ## while last item != 0 (always true)
     A      ## print the most recently calculated Fibonacci number
      C+    ## push the sum of the last two items of the stack
```

This one is a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

## [Detour](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html), 20 bytes

This one is going for the "infinite sequence" option.

```
v1vq:$
  $+
p,p^
^ q
```

[Try it online!](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html?hex=djF2cTokCiAgJCsKcCxwXgpeIHE%3D)

Branch 1 takes a number, prints it, adds it with the number from Branch 2, then puts the result in Branch 2
Branch 2 takes a number, feeds it to the addition with branch 1 then puts the original number (*not* the sum) in Branch 1.

For a better explanation click the link and you'll see it in action.

More "readable" version:

## [Detour](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html), 267 bytes

```py
:$v  1v   q   # split into branches

          +   # push sum of last 2 fibonacci numbers to branch 2
      {  

  p , p   ^   # print branch 1, merge with branch 3

      }

  ^   q       # push branch 2 into branch 1 for printing and recycling

# 1   2   3
```

[Try it online!](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html?hex=OiR2ICAxdiAgIHEgICAjIHNwbGl0IGludG8gYnJhbmNoZXMKICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICArICAgIyBwdXNoIHN1bSBvZiBsYXN0IDIgZmlib25hY2NpIG51bWJlcnMgdG8gYnJhbmNoIDIKICAgICAgeyAgCgogIHAgICxwICAgXiAgICMgcHJpbnQgYnJhbmNoIDEsIG1lcmdlIHdpdGggYnJhbmNoIDMKCiAgICAgIH0KCiAgXiAgIHEgICAgICAgIyBwdXNoIGJyYW5jaCAyIGludG8gYnJhbmNoIDEgZm9yIHByaW50aW5nIGFuZCByZWN5Y2xpbmcKCiMgMSAgIDIgICAz)

Answer (score 1):

## [Oration](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Assorted-Programming-Languages/tree/master/oration), 135 bytes

I believe that this is "optimal"... *takes a deep breath* here we go!

```
Inhale
Start a function f with n
If n<2
Return n
Backtracking
Inhale
Here
Literally, f(n-2)+f(n-1)
I'm done
Listen
Invoke f with number
```

The little `~>` is input. This outputs the (input)th Fibonacci number. This transpiles to (in Python):

```
def f(n):
    if n<2:
        return  n
    return f(n-2)+f(n-1) 
print(f(eval(input("~>"))))
```

Comment: Why is the transpiled Python code not golfed D:

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL 9.2, 80 bytes

```
SELECT ROUND(POWER((1+SQRT(5))/2,LEVEL-1)/SQRT(5))FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<:1;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 51 bytes

`function f(n) return n<2 and n or f(n-1)+f(n-2)end`

It creates a function called `f(n)`, that takes an input (`n`). If n = 1, returns n. This function uses recursion.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, noncompeting, 11 bytes

```
0X{_@+}q~*;
```

Comment: **F(0) = 0**. You should eliminate the backslash.

Comment: Ah I was assuming that we were starting from `1,1.....` so I guess this is a good convention since it saves a byte :)

Comment: People *start* the Fibonacci sequence at different values, so **F(0) = 0** may or may not be defined. However, when it comes to indexing, **F(1), F(2) = 1**, since a lot of the sequence's properties depend on that.

Answer (score 1):

## [DUP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/DUP), 10 bytes

```
1$[^^+2!]!
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html)</kbd>

An infinite stream that leaves results on stack. Use the <kbd>Step</kbd> button to avoid setting off the infinite loop.

## Explanation

```
1$         {start w/ 2 1's}
  [     ]! {execute lambda}
   ^^      {take top 2 items on stack}
     +     {add them}
      2!   {self recurse!}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gogh](https://github.com/zachgates7/Gogh), 10 bytes

```
¹Ƥ{Ƥ÷®+Ø}x
```

Executed from the command line like this:

```
$ ./gogh "" "¹Ƥ{Ƥ÷®+Ø}x"
```

---

#### Explanation

```
¹       “ Push two ones to the stack.                 ”
Ƥ       “ Print the TOS.                              ”
{       “ Open a code block.                          ”
 Ƥ      “ Print the TOS.                              ”
 ÷      “ Duplicate the TOS.                          ”
 ®      “ Rotate the stack leftward.                  ”
 +      “ Destructively add the TOS to the STOS.      ”
 Ø      “ Loop all preceding code (within the block). ”
}       “ Close a code block.                         ”
x       “ Execute the TOS.                            ”
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scratch, 106 characters

This isn't impressive at all but someone had to do it.

[image: scratch blocks]

```
when gf clicked
add[1]to[f v
forever
 add((item[last v]of[f v])+(item((length of[f v])-(1))of[f v]))to[f v
```

[scratchblocks2 render](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#when%20gf%20clicked%0Aadd%5B1%5Dto%5Bf%20v%0Aforever%0A%20add((item%5Blast%20v%5Dof%5Bf%20v%5D)%2B(item((length%20of%5Bf%20v%5D)-(1))of%5Bf%20v%5D))to%5Bf%20v)

Fairly bog-standard solution. "f" is a list which starts off empty. Runs as long as you let it.

Since it's not easy to define what is and isn't a "character" in Scratch I've used the forum plugin's formatting. This allows me to cheat off some additional characters (scratchblocks2 is very lenient with dropping closing parenthesis, "end"s, and shaving off whitespace here and there)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cy](https://github.com/cyoce/Cy), 11 + 1 (`-p` flag) = 12 bytes (non-competing)

This is going for the infinite stream

```
0 1 $&+ &do
```

(the `-p` flag implicitly prints every non-block value pushed to the stack)

Literally,

- push 0

  - print it
- push 1

  - print it
- forever

  - push the sum of the last two items
  - print it

Without the `-p` flag semi-cheat:

## [Cy](https://github.com/cyoce/Cy), 24 bytes

```
0 &:< 1 &:< {&+ &:<} &do
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Alpax](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Alpax), 5 bytes (non-competing)

Non-competing since the language postdates the challenge. Code:

```
⇇+
1¹
```

Yes, that's right mates. My newest invention, which is more mathematically based than 05AB1E. This language uses a *lot* of recursion, so be aware. This is a bit like a stack based language, but a little bit different. The elaborated version of the above code is:

```
a(n) = ⇇+
a(0) = 1, a(1) = 1
```

Explanation:

```
⇇ is short for pushing a(n - 1), a(n - 2)
+ adds both functions up.
```

It then implicitly prints the result of `a(n)`, whereas `n` is the input.

Uses the [**Alpax**](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Alpax/blob/master/code-page.md) encoding.

Comment: Alpax doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: The Alpax repo is gone. Umm, is this language converted into Oasis?

Comment: @Λ̸̸ Alpax is/was a different language and a public repository is not available anymore. Oasis was another attempt at a golfing language specialized in sequences, which became a bit more successful and 'took over' the place of Alpax.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 20 bytes

```julia
!n=n>1?!~-n+!~-~-n:n
```

Straightforward implementation of the recursive definition. No match for the [matrix approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75665), but a lovely opportunity to abuse Julia's ability to [redefine operators](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81028).

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=IW49bj4xPyF-LW4rIX4tfi1uOm4KCnByaW50KCEyMCk&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Sesos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos), 11 bytes (non-competing)

Not in-place, linear memory.

Hexdump:

```
0000000: ae8583 ef6bc7 045fe7 b907                         ....k.._...

Size   : 11 byte(s)
```

[Try it online!](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=c2V0IG51bWluCnNldCBudW1vdXQKYWRkIDEscndkIDEsZ2V0ICAgIDtzZXR1cCB0YXBlCmptcAogIGZ3ZCAxCiAgam1wLHN1YiAxLGZ3ZCAxLGFkZCAxLGZ3ZCAxLGFkZCAxLHJ3ZCAyLGpuegogIHJ3ZCAxCiAgc3ViIDEKICBqbXAsc3ViIDEsZndkIDEsYWRkIDEscndkIDEsam56CiAgZndkIDEKam56CmZ3ZCAyCnB1dA&input=MTI&debug=on)

### Assembler

```lisp
set numin
set numout
add 1,rwd 1,get    ;setup tape
jmp
  fwd 1
  jmp,sub 1,fwd 1,add 1,fwd 1,add 1,rwd 2,jnz
  rwd 1
  sub 1
  jmp,sub 1,fwd 1,add 1,rwd 1,jnz
  fwd 1
jnz
fwd 2
put
```

Answer (score 1):

## Maple, 27 bytes

```
ifelse(n<3,1,f(n-1)+f(n-2))
```

Usage:

```
> f := n -> ifelse(n<3,1,f(n-1)+f(n-2));
> f(2);
  1
> f(3);
  2
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 71 chars

Single number: (Binet formula, considering 1.62 as the golden ratio))

```
int f(int n){return(Math.pow(1.62,n)-(Math.pow(-1.62,-n))/Math.sqrt(5)}
```

I know this isn't surprisingly short, however Math is beautiful and this formula is even more!

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby

### Ungolfed, 60 bytes

```
def fib(prev,nxt)
  x = prev + nxt
  puts x
  fib(nxt,x)
end
```

### Golfed, 33 bytes

```
def f(a,b)x=a+b;puts x;f(b,x)end
```

Pretty simple to call, use `f(first, next)`.

Comment: You can still golf it further. Try taking out the unnecessary whitespace. Also, there are some good tips [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby)

Comment: `x=a+b;puts x` can become `puts x=a+b`

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8 29 bytes

Using Java 8 lambdas. This is a valid statement if there exists a function interface with a method that returns an int and takes an int as a parameter. Also the variable that stores the lambda must be declared as a member (static or non static) of the class it is in so that it can be used recursively.

```
f=n->n<2?0:f.f(n-1)+f.f(n-2);
```

### Ungolfed:

```
@FunctionalInterface interface F
{
    int f(int n);
}

public class Main
{
    static F f;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        f=n->n<2?0:f.f(n-1)+f.f(n-2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Prismatic](http://www.ostracodfiles.com/prismatic/main.html), 113 bytes (can be smaller)

```
right wideness wideness left forward up vertex longness backward right vertex tallness forward down vertex vertex
```

Inspired by Brainfuck, Cubix and Hexagony.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 75 bytes

```
a=[1,1]
while True:
    a.append(a[-1]+a[-2])
    a.pop(0)
    print(a[-2])
```

Yes, I know, way too big, but I don't know golfing languages that well.

Comment: 1) `while True` can be replaced with `while 1`. 2) You only need one space of indentation. 3) The while loop contents can be replaced with `print(a[0]);a=[a[1],sum(a)]` (on the same line as the `while` statement). 4) The parentheses on the `print` call can be removed if you're using Python 2. With all these tricks applied: `a=[1,1]\nwhile 1:print(a[0]);a=[a[1],sum(a)]` (replace the `'\n'` with a literal newline).

Comment: If you take Mego's approach you can replace `a=[a[1],sum(a)]` with `a=a[1],sum(a)` to save two bytes.  This works because the comma creates an implicit tuple rather than a literal list.

Comment: The same can also be done with `a=[1,1]`.  It can be shortened to `a=1,1`

Answer (score 1):

## [Stackish](http://www.enderscythe.com/projects/proglangs/stackish/), 12 bytes

```
01d\+.qzcl2'
```

How it works:

```
0   Load 0 into stack (stack now 0).
1   Load 1 into stack (stack now 0,1).
d   Duplicate last number of stack (stack now 0,1,1).
\   Swap bottom with top (stack now 1,0,1).
+   Add last two numbers (stack now 1,1).
.   Pop to output (stack now 1).
q   Undo pop (stack now 1,1).
z   Pause.
c   Clear screen.
l2' Jump to 2nd character (d).

d   Duplicate last number of stack (stack now 1,1,1).
\   Swap bottom with top (stack now 1,1,1).
+   Add last two numbers (stack now 1,2).
.   Pop to output (stack now 1).
q   Undo pop (stack now 1,2).
z   Pause.
c   Clear screen.
l2' Jump to 2nd character (d)

...
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby (as function) 31 bytes

```
->n{a,b=1,0;n.times{a=b+b=a};b}
```

Comment: This is byte-per-byte exactly the same as another answer.

Comment: Yes, it was. I commented on the other answer and wrote mine before the original author accepted my suggestion. Now I am only leaving the function, because I could not find any ruby function in 5 randomly-sorted pages of answers.

Comment: @VoteToClose Duplicate answers [are allowed](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10812/31716).

Comment: My code was mostly stolen from the other answer, with a little improvement (which is now also in the original post), and my answer was written much later. I am leaving the function because I could not find another.

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 40 bytes

<sup>The language is much newer than question, of course.</sup>

```
(d f(q((x y)(i(disp x)1(f y(a x y
(f 0 1
```

This is a full program that outputs Fibonacci numbers until you stop it. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/18jRSFNo1BDo0KhUlMjUyMFKKhQoWmokaZQqZGoABTlAjINFAz//wcA)

The first line defines a function `f` that takes numbers `x` and `y`, outputs `x`, and calls `f` recursively on `y` and the `a`ddition of `x` and `y`. The main trick is the use of `i`f to simulate a "do A, then B" structure: the `disp` call is used as the condition; its return is always falsey; so we put the recursion in the false branch.

The second line calls `f` with 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 11 bytes

*This was a collaborative golfing effort with Sp3000.*

```
1 \ O
,+{.3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@2@oEKPgz6WjXa1n/P8/AA)

This prints the Fibonacci sequence indefinitely, starting from `1,1`, one integer on a line. Unfortunately, it's horrible in terms of memory, because it leaks one stringified copy of each number in the sequence. The things you do for bytes...

#### Explanation

```
1   Push 1 to initialise the sequence. There's already an implicit zero underneath.
\   Reflect to NE. Switch to Ordinal.
    Immediately reflect off top boundary, move SE.

    The remainder of the program runs in an infinite loop. At this point of the loop
    there's the current number F_n of the sequence on top of the stack, and the 
    previous number F_n-1 is below.

                                                            Stack:
                                                            [... F_n-1 F_n] 
.   Implicitly convert F_n to a string and duplicate it.    [... F_n-1 "F_n" "F_n"]
    Reflect off bottom boundary, move NE.
O   Output F_n with a trailing linefeed.                    [... F_n-1 "F_n"]
    Reflect off top right corner, move back SW.
.   Make another copy of F_n. (We don't need this one.)     [... F_n-1 "F_n" "F_n"]
    Reflect off bottom boundary, move NW.
\   Reflect to S. Switch to Cardinal.
{   Turn 90 degrees left, i.e. east.
.   Implicitly convert F_n to an integer and duplicate it.  [... F_n-1 "F_n" F_n F_n]
3   Push 3.                                                 [... F_n-1 "F_n" F_n F_n 3]
,   Pull up the third stack element, which is F_n-1.        [... "F_n" F_n F_n F_n-1]
+   Add F_n and F_n-1.                                      [... "F_n" F_n F_n+1]  
{   Turn 90 degrees left, i.e. north.
\   Reflect to SE. Switch to Ordinal.

    After this point, the loop repeats.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, 113 bytes

```
f(n:NNI):NNI==(n=0=>0;n:=n-1;x:=sqrt(5);floor(numeric(((x+1)/(2*x))*((1+x)/2)^n+((x-1)/(2*x))*((1-x)/2)^n)))::INT
```

code for test and results

```
(80) -> [f(i)  for i in 0..20]
   (80)
   [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765]
                                            Type: List NonNegativeInteger
(81) -> f 100
   (81)  354224848179261915076
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
(82) -> f 200
   (82)  280571172992510140037336354957747795525632
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
(83) -> f 400
   (83)
  1760236806450139664680709294813170892283658770059881093310828506440687624218_
   31925760
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
(84) -> f 800
   (84)
  6928308186422471713609360660466569632290421684876894264783997577258487494487_
   420363654234099779749410573113727333378633545181944038619446626409501657425_
   3135847342735360
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
(85) -> f 1500
   (85)
  1355112566856310195162377575526951323656561770431639555079987987810736653460_
   922122221302671882558120755439823360357867711740787668744312284056217232330_
   713983569575833249689158528416736647370129969548463847884661978641646883591_
   466734576231634867107272686298047871451723693301109753896341229444935835304_
   2229054930944
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
(86) -> f 2000
   (86)
  4224696333392304878698067179976673472756391964001565086095500593531167791551_
   743662247281607190958887487440686606420026093467732621145548367502217030083_
   858092272596709322168369132666938424515347258074945014044152199085287931830_
   556530989999311940427567701708311778838430925973655760228465275886647451746_
   556255968313014088560151159533857580044154666168801306507492995800168547537_
   206536250047308876795741658264221262020608
```

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, 35 bytes

```
a(0)==0;a(1)==1;a(n)==a(n-1)+a(n-2)
```

above it is one succession defined by Recurrence... Results

```
(7) -> [a(i)  for i in 0..20]
   (7)  [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 864 bytes

```
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:W 1 L 2 R 1 L 1 L 2 L.Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Sunny Skies Park:W 1 R.[a]Go to Cyclone:N 1 L.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Fueler Up:N 2 R, 2 R.Go to The Babelfishery:S.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:N 1 L 1 R.Go to Sunny Skies Park:S 1 R 1 L 1 R.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:N 1 L.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Addition Alley:N 2 R 1 R.Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park."," is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:N 1 L 1 L.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Sunny Skies Park:N 2 R.Switch to plan "a".
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/taxi#lZJPT8QgEMW/yqQXLxuS9djbqtFLszaLZg/GA9JpS4pAgGbTT19L/2zcrtZ6AcI85s37hXYLwsGJCS9UAcwD9czyUsgM9vUnWi110ZBVoicNXv9Yio@whQRu4dDvwzkhqeBVbYCBYc6hKtBCoYNDaFMr1QCtBDpIma0WxfcNl1rhNMHsae9@IG/sfaiP6ngfBlns@1Ii3LEPlLlwJdpmUbzLso6PVrCTEicajzXKTvRqOrcu/iYsY2nePKaL7VPtPDznueBTzm83Q5Y@5i8MaCieRethroc1y7/e4vLhAOrPKa/@R7SJZp/0aIVHe@PgAY32o9nl5Zlb8k/2V3z7qQk9Cc/LIDCSKYhYRNr2Cw)

Ungolfed:

```
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Starchild Numerology: west 1st left 2nd right 1st left 1st left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Sunny Skies Park: west 1st right.
[a]
Go to Cyclone: north 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Fueler Up: north 2nd R, 2nd right.
Go to The Babelfishery: south.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: north 1st left 1st right.
Go to Sunny Skies Park: south 1st right 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: north 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Addition Alley: north 2nd right 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
"," is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Writer's Depot: north 1st left 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Sunny Skies Park: north 2nd right.
Switch to plan "a".
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 23 bytes

```
1!_# @.!_[# @!+!_<1+>];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//fUDFeWcFBTzE@GkgpaivG2xhq28Va//8PAA)

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//fwFAxPlpZwUFRWzHexlDbLvb/fwA "Braingolf – Try It Online")

Comment: [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//fwDBaMV5RW1nBQcHQLvb/fwA "Braingolf – Try It Online")

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//fWNfQMFpRO/b///@GxgA "Braingolf – Try It Online") for output the `n`th number

Answer (score 1):

## [Joy](http://www.latrobe.edu.au/humanities/research/research-projects/past-projects/joy-programming-language), 45 bytes

```
DEFINE f ==[2<][][[1 - f][2 - f]cleave+]ifte.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8qv/P/fxdXN089VIU3B1jbayCY2OjY62lBBVyEtNtoITCXnpCaWpWrHZqaVpOr9N1NI0@MqLM0s@Q8A) Zero-indexed. Example usage: `6 f` yields `8`.

```
[2<]                         ifte . if the top stack element is less than two  
    []                            . then do nothing
      [              cleave ]     . else duplicate the element and apply two functions
                           +      . and sum the results
       [1 - f][2 - f]             . where the functions compute the two previous Fibonacci numbers
```

---

**Alternative** (same byte count):

```
DEFINE f ==[2<][][dup 1 - f swap 2 - f+]ifte.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 6 bytes

```
=1:z+y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39bQqkq78v9/AA)

This works both with and without input - it prints the sequence without input, and the `n`th item (1-indexed) with input `n`.

For `0, 1, 1, ...` version, **8 bytes**:

```
=0,1:z+y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39ZAx9CqSrvy/38A)

## Explanation

```
=1      Set first item in sequence to 1
  :     Mode: Sequence 1 (prints sequence with no input, or nth item with input n
   z+y  Each term equals the previous two terms added together (defaults to 0)
```

I really, really like the way this language is going :)

Comment: Note current version uses `Z` and `Y` instead of `z` and `y`

Answer (score 1):

## ReRegex, 50 bytes.

```
(0+),(0+):0/$1,$2,$1$2:/.*?(0+),0+:$/$1/0,0:#input
```

0 indexed. Takes input and gives output via Unary.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/X8NAW1MHRFgZ6KsY6qgY6agYqhhZ6etp2YOlDLStVIAS@gY6BlbKmXkFpSX//xuAAAA)

### About the Program

ReRegex was designed to be much like an advanced version of [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////). It offers the same very basic concept of repeatedly doing string match and replace operations. However, that's where the similarities end. ReRegex instead uses a list of match and replace operations, separated by `/`s, to perform in a loop, and the original string to effect. The Regexes will continue being performed on the original string until a constant state is achieved, at which point the program will dump the string to STDOUT.

This program in particular is just 2 regular expressions and then the input with some default values.

```
(0+),(0+):0  -> $1,$2,$1$2:
.*?(0+),0+:$ -> $1
```

And the input is formatted with;

```
0,0:#input
```

ReRegex defaultly replaces `#input` with whatever is passed to the program on STDIN.

For an example, let's say `00000` is passed to STDIN. First, the "Memory" looks like this:

```
0,0:00000
```

In the first loop, the regex `(0+),(0+):0` is matched, the replace then creates the next itteration of the fibonnachi sequence.

```
0,0,00:0000
```

And in doing so, it also pops one of the 0's off, which is why `:0` is at the tail end of the match, but not the replace. This then happens 4 more times in a row.

```
0,0,00,000,00000,00000000,0000000000000:
```

Now that first regex doesn't match, as there's no more :0 at the end, so we're almost at a stable end point. Now that there's nothing after `:`, `.*?(0+),0+:$` matches, and all it does is clear all data but the *second last* group of `0`s.

```
00000000
```

Now, nothing else matches, so it's outputted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Joy](http://www.latrobe.edu.au/humanities/research/research-projects/past-projects/joy-programming-language), 28 bytes

```
[2<][][1 - dup 1 -][+]binrec
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8qv/G/2P9rIJjY6NtpQQVchpbRAAUjHRmvHJmXmFaUm/9fj@g8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Forth, <s>39</s> 36 bytes

```
0 1 : f BEGIN 2DUP + ROT . AGAIN ; f
```

#### Explanation

First 0 and 1 are pushed to the stack.
Then starts an endless loop where `2DUP` duplicates the top two stack items which are then summed with `+`. At this point stack is `0 1 1`. Then the bottom item of the stack is moved on top with `ROT`. `.` prints and removes the item on the top of the stack. Creates an endless sequence of Fibonacci numbers.

Had to check out what's Forth about. And is there a better way to learn than 
trying to golf Fibonacci series. I see that there's already an answer with Forth but desided to post anyway. At least this is a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 24 bytes

```
f=a=>a<2?1:f(a-1)+f(a-2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@@/wP8020dYu0cbI3tAqTSNR11BTG0QZaf4vKMrMK9FI0zA0MDDQ1PwPAA)

(Not working on TIO yet; waiting for pull)

The `@` is not necessary but it enables caching for the lambda which makes it considerably faster (as in, it actually finishes in a reasonable amount of time). That being said, when I tried computing it up to `10000` (which I needed to increase `sys.setrecursionlimit` to do), it gave me a `Segmentation Fault` because the program ran out of memory (Proton is very inefficient) :P

Comment: Polyglot with ES6.

Comment: @Zacharý Huh that's cool. This is weird; Proton is often a polyglot with Python too :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Tampio](https://github.com/fergusq/tampio), 107 bytes

```
uni on 1 lisättynä 1:een lisättynä yhteenlaskuun sovellettuna unen jäseniin ja unen hännän jäseniin
```

Explanation:

```
uni on 1 lisättynä 1:een lisättynä
uni =  1 :         1     :

yhteenlaskuun sovellettuna  unen jäseniin ja unen hännän jäseniin
(+)           `zip`        (uni           ,  tail uni            )
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 16 bytes

```
<a3:1!+#~a$#~~a$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P/fJtHYylBRW7kuUUW5Dkj8/29oBAA)

## Explanation:

```
<a3:1!+#~a$#~~a$
<a3:1            - If a<3 then 1
     !           - Else
      +          - Sum
       #~a$      - Call Self but with parameter a-1, will be replaced by result
           #~~a$ - Call self but with parameter a-2, will be replaced by result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>36</s> <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```
({}(())){({}[()]<(({})<>{})>)}<>
```

Outputs the `n`th number of the zero indexed Fibonacci sequence (`F(0) = 1, F(1) = 1, etc.`)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6VkNDU1OzGsiI1tCMtdEAMjRt7ICEnWatjd3//wYA)

### Explanation coming soon...

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, 12 Bytes

```
10:r+:nao20.
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
3
5
...
```

Could save 2 bytes by removing the new line, but then there would be no separation in the output at all.

### Explanation:

Pretty basic. Start by pushing 1, 0 to the stack. Duplicate the top item, reverse the stack, and sum the top two items. If we had f_n, f_n-1 on the stack before, we now have f_n+1, f_n. Duplicate the top item, and print it.
'ao' prints a new line. '20.' moves the pointer to (2,0) in the codebox, which is right after the '10'. Start again.

Answer (score 1):

## QBasic, 32 bytes

```
b=1
DO
?b
b=b+a
a=b-a
SLEEP
LOOP
```

Generates and prints Fibonacci numbers forever. `SLEEP` waits for a user keypress between numbers; otherwise, the output would scroll off the screen very rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 74 bytes

```
D,f,@@@@*,V$2D+G1+dAppp=0$Qp{f}p
D,r,@,¿1=,1,bM¿
D,g,@,¿1_,1_001${f},1¿{r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HAQi0dMJUjFy03Q21UxwLCgpsDVQCC6rTagu4XHSKdBx0Du03tNUx1EnyPbQfKJIOEYnXMYw3MDBUAarTMTy0v7qo9v///4YG//ILSjLz84r/6@pm5hbkZCZnlgCZxQWpyZlplbbpAA)

---

## Old version, 75 bytes

```
D,f,@@@@*,V$2D+G1+dAppp=0$Qp{f}p
D,r,@:,1b]$oVcGbM
x:?
-1
I,$f>x>0>1>0
$r>x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcExCoAwDADAPe/IpBEax4JRoSAODi7dHNTS1eBUEN8evdtTUjULlGn4VRSxDfXEdRpVtXO46pNfhUA3DZ742PCK53QsUHwPDcNMmKWIExYHeEsxM3Yf)

It's long, but I rather this than have a builtin. Takes a single input `n`, and outputs the `n`the Fibonacci number.

### How it works

Executable demonstration with an example input of `8`:

```
D,fib,@@@@*,	; Create a tetradic function 'fib'
		; This returns the nth and (n-1)th fib number
		; Example arguments:	[8 0 1 0]
	V	; Save the top value;	[8 0 1]	  ; 0
	$	; Swap;			[8 1 0]	  ; 0
	2D	; Take the 2nd value;	[8 1 0 1] ; 0
	+	; Sum;			[8 1 1]	  ; 0
	G	; Retrieve;		[8 1 1 0]
	1+	; Increment;		[8 1 1 1]
	d	; Duplicate;		[8 1 1 1 1]
	A	; Push the arguments;	[8 1 1 1 1 8 0 1 0]
	ppp	; Pop 3 values;		[8 1 1 1 1 8]
	=	;   Cond: Equal?	[8 1 1 1 0]
	0$Qp	;   If: Return 0
	{fib}p	;   Else: Call 'fib' again
                ; Eventually, this returns:
		;	[7 13 21 7 0]

D,ret,@:,	; Create a monadic function 'ret' that outputs the final result
		; Example argument:	[[7 13 21 7 0]]
	1b]	; Push [1];		[[7 13 21 7 0] [1]]
	$	; Swap;			[[1] [7 13 21 7 0]]
	o	; Logical OR;		[[1] [7 13 21 7 0]]
	VcG	; Clear all but one;	[[7 13 21 7 0]]
	bM	; Take the maximum;	[21]

x:?		; Take input;		x = 8
-1		; Decrement;		x = 7
I,		; If x != 0:
	$fib>x	;	Call 'fib'	x = [7 13 21 7 0]
	>0>1>0	; 
$ret>x		; Call 'ret'		x = 21
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJdi5tAFH0ef8UtBNIPF5zsQ4KS7JYklEBL223Zl@DDRMdEOo5TnUldSn@7vVc3axJan2TOued@nCPS1Ji2XflZvvPv8XvrswiWlRRWggArbSXSPIHM6cTmpYYxEsceQ9L3Q15DJa2rdA32IEHbAwidwmt9w9/gPzJBu2Inq46/bkRhFKpWe1dIbeuQbWcQAIcg9tgjMr6Jo@yUbGngKJST0TMlZgARBB4bEe2XMBFjBFHtCZqsaCjxo5eY4CCDBO9Eet47knDFi8Ig/gGRB9w4l0cse0a76TgVbXRSSZp8wDhiKUIrZ1Se4M3OoA58j@AXVx@6mV42j85IMNzAGEN0XP62n72@kIMZcubIAFiWOg1h/dMJdTcwSCMYfTUdZZOFtAy6Q6v9RjP@9MBa1TKEpVCqNxPEXuTag6sPDTvirNhBPfk4/mB2SHay7RT4LUw4TKmvt/IR9e/Di/gUpb5KD5LGKCYslM4aZ/vkZLkWCuVrp@w/s4JRuehHluzi0223PKZDXTDoMb7KCz7BtUyJhI/lHs1T8Pkh@g/rMaFsLJUUFdDhdg4X0JSta@bu03kKC9HkBWVtO8E0eE14x05wrnF97NfAHGbeDSdgJYeE0fvU2/j0vsmggVdzCPD0I/Rs0aABg4Md99IPtggWfBFgrTfCm2MBzd9VkAW9/IS3bTv7Cw)

Answer (score 1):

## FALSE, 13 bytes

```
1 1[1][$2ø+]#
```

Numbers are pushed to the stack.

Answer (score 1):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 28 bytes

```
def f(a=1,b=1)=[a]::f(b,a+b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfn/PyU1TSFNI9HWUCfJ1lDTNjox1soqTSNJJ1E7SfN/moamQo2dQm5igYpGQVFmXgmYC9RZXJqb@h8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forked](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Forked), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
01v
  >sP+%A!"U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svyk5N@f/fwLCMS0HBrjhAW9VRUSn0/38A)

This uses the same method as my [Implicit answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142476/61563).

The first line sets up the stack: pushes `0`, pushes `1`, and then directs the control flow South.

The `>` on the second line turns the IP East where it hits the main code:

```
sP+%A!"U
```

- `s` - swap top two stack values
- `P` - pop top of stack, store in register
- `+` - pop top two stack values, add together, push result
- `%` - print top of stack as integer
- `A!` - print 0xA as codepoint character (ASCII newline)
- `"` - swap top two stack values
- `U` - push register to stack

Since the IP wraps, this line is executed infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 23 bytes

```
.+
$*
+`11(1*)
1$1 $1
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLSzvB0FDDUEuTy1DFUEHFkMvw/38DLkMuIy5jLhMuUy4zLnMuCy5LLkMDAA) Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
+`11(1*)
1$1 $1
```

Repeatedly replace all `n` greater than 1 with copies of `n-1` and `n-2`, thus calculating `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)` for n greater than 1.

```
1
```

Count the remaining `1`s, as `f(0) = 0` and `f(1) = 1`.

Comment: 4 days ago I set out to implement Fibonacci in Retina using emulation of the `^(.|..)*$` partition counting method. After golfing it down it turned out to be [almost exactly the same as yours](https://tio.run/##Dci5DYAwFETB/NVhJGNLiPXBIQqgDRMQkBAg@v8w4Tzne92HdX5vNkRcIDav0Eu4qM1FZDYiEplCZWJmYUV/CiWUUUH1Aw) at the same size in bytes, except that I was thinking about it differently at a conceptual level.

Answer (score 1):

## [µ6](https://github.com/bforte/mu6), 16 bytes

```
[>#[,.[+.]][[,>[#/0[+/1]<>]]/1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy01@/8/2k45WkcvWlsvNjY6WscuWlnfIFpb3zDWxi42FkjF/v//39gAAA)

#### Explanation

```
[>                               -- right element of the tuple generated by
  #                              -- | primitive recursive function
                                 -- | base case:
   [,                            -- | | pair of
     .                           -- | | | constant zero
     [+.]                        -- | | | successor of constant zero
   ]                             -- | | : (0,1)
                                 -- | recursive case:
   [                             -- | | compose the two
    [,                           -- | | | pair of
     >                           -- | | | | the right element
     [#/0[+/1]<>]                -- | | | | add left & right element
    ]                            -- | | | (snd, fst + snd)
    /1                           -- | | | second argument (we only need the tuple)
   ]                             -- | : (f (n-1), f (n-2) + f (n-1))
]                                -- : f n
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86 assembly (32-bit), 14 bytes

Bytecode:

```
58 59 50 41 31 c0 99 40 01 c2 92 e2 fb c3
```

That 3-byte add/xchg is quite concise :-)

1-indexed.

```
0:   58                      pop    %eax
1:   59                      pop    %ecx
2:   50                      push   %eax
3:   41                      inc    %ecx
4:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
6:   99                      cltd   
7:   40                      inc    %eax
8:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
a:   92                      xchg   %eax,%edx
b:   e2 fb                   loop   8
d:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: how does this output?

Answer (score 1):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 15 bytes

```
1loN+{<
>\:O\:^
```

Uses signed 32-bit ints so eventually reaches overflow and wraps negative. Starts at 0, which is technically correct?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/98wJ99Pu9qGyy7Gyj/GKu7/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tidy](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Tidy), 15 bytes

```
recur2(1,1,(+))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8lMqfyfpmBl@78oNbm0yEjDUMdQR0NbU/N/cUZ@uUaa5n8A) Returns an infintie range of Fibonacci numbers.

### Explanation

`recur2` defines a recursive function which takes the previous `2` items and applies a function to them, in the case, addition. This is equivalent to saying "the first two entries are both `1` and every entry after that is the sum of the previous two".

Answer (score 1):

## [Alumin](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Alumin), 19 bytes

```
zhdnqhhhhhdaodradnp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8wpzc3M@/@/KiMlrzADBFIS81OKElPyCv7/BwA)

### Explanation

```
zhdnqhhhhhdaodradnp
zh                    push 0, 1                 [0, 1]
  dn                  output 1                  [0, 1]
    q             p   loop (forever)            
     hhhhh            push 5                    [0, 1, 5]
          da          double (10)               [0, 1, 10]
            o         output as char (newline)  [0, 1]
             d        duplicate TOS             [0, 1, 1]
              r       reverse stack             [1, 1, 0]
               a      add top two               [1, 1]
                dn    output top w/out popping  [1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 70 bytes

```pascal
var i,j:word;begin i:=1;repeat writeln(i);i:=i+j;j:=i-j until 1<0 end.
```

[Try it online! (limited)](https://tio.run/##DchBCoAgEADAr@yxKMOOKfWXTbfYRUzM8vnWaWAS3g6DOpJr7cUMPIqpV/Z2p5MjsFlnmykRFqiZC4XYcW//5kGs/CiBJxYOwNuitQaKfmrtAw)

Prints the sequence forever, 1-indexed.

#### Explanation:

```pascal
var i,j:word;   //declare 2 integers, i and j;
                //word gives range [0,65535];
                //for bigger ranges, you can use Int32, Int64 or QWord
begin
  i:=1;         //set i to 1
                //j has not been set, so it gets 0 as initial value
  repeat        //start a block to be repeated (first time enters unconditionally)
    writeln(i); //write current value of i with a newline to separate numbers
                //i needs to get the value of the next number, which is obtained by adding i and j
    i:=i+j;     //j is used to keep track of the last written value
    j:=i-j      //which is used in the next iteration;
                //since i is now the sum of 2 previous values in the sequence
                //and j is the earlier one, the later one can be obtained
                //by substracting current j from i
  until 1<0     //end a block to be repeated
                //condition is always false, so the program will loop in repeat block forever
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 100 characters

```
|n|{let mut a=1u64;let mut b=1u64;let mut s=vec![a,b];for _ in 0..n {let t=b;b=a+b;a=t;s.push(b);}s}
```

A closure that takes an integer n as input and returns a vector of the first n items of the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: You could shave off a few bytes given the fact that you don't have to return all the Fibonacci numbers, just the `n`th one.

Answer (score 1):

## [Little Man Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_man_computer), 45 bytes, 8 instructions

> Note: both answers only work up to \$ f(15) = 987 \$, as the maximum value for an integer in LMC is \$ 999 \$.

The first solution generates Fibonacci numbers 'indefinitely':

```
LDA 7
ADD 8
STA 7
SUB 8
STA 8
OUT
BRA 0
DAT 1
```

and is assembled into RAM as

```
507 108 307 208 308 902 600 001
```

### 86 bytes, 14 instructions

The second solution returns the Fibonacci number at the index given (0-based indexing):

```
INP
STA 0
LDA 12
ADD 14
STA 12
SUB 14
STA 14
LDA 0
SUB 13
BRP 1
LDA 14
OUT
DAT 1
DAT 1
```

...which is assembled into RAM as:

```
901 300 512 114 312 214 314 500 213 801 514 902 001 001
```

You can test these on the online simulator [here](https://peterhigginson.co.uk/lmc/).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 43 Bytes

```
a,c=0,0;b=1
while 1:print(a);c=a+b;a=b;b=c
```

Comment: Note that Python has a swap statement to avoid having to use an extra variable: `a,b=b,a+b`. Also, there are plenty of shorter Python answers already posted.

Comment: Also, 0 isn't supposed to be included in this challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pure](https://github.com/agraef/pure-lang), 66 bytes

```
using system;do(printf"%Zd\n")(f 1L 1L with f a b=a:f b(a+b)&end);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KygtSv3/v7Q4My9dobiyuCQ11zolX6OgKDOvJE1JNSolJk9JUyNNwdAHhMozSzIU0hQSFZJsE63SFJI0ErWTNNVS81I0rf//BwA)

First answer in Pure \o/

Prints until TIO stops it or the heat death of the universe, whatever comes first.

#### How:

```
using system;do(printf"%Zd\n")(f 1L 1L with f a b=a:f b(a+b)&end); // Anonymous lambda;
using system;                                                      // Import system functions
             do                                                    // Infinite loop
               (printf"%Zd\n")                                     // Print bigints + linefeed
                              (f 1L 1L                             // Declare f with 2 bigint args
                                                                   // starting with 1
                                       with f a b=                 // with f(a,b) being
                                                  a:f b(a+b)       // a list from a until f(b,(a+b));
                                                            &      // transformed into a stream
                                                                   // to prevent overflowing
                                                             end);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 37 bytes

Prints the n'th term using the closed form.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

```r
function(n,s=5^.5)round((s/2+.5)^n/s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9PI0@n2NY0Ts9Usyi/NC9FQ6NY30gbyIvL0y/W/J@mYWhlZKD5HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Awk, 35 bytes

```
BEGIN{for(y=1;z=x+y;y=z)print(x=y)}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686Lb9Io9LW0LrKtkK70rrStkqzoCgzr0SjwrZSs/b/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [\/\/>](https://github.com/torcado194/worm), 9 bytes

```
:@+1}:nau
```

Outputs infinitely starting from 0, with each number on a new line.

#### Explanation:

```
:           Dupe top of stack
 @          Rotate the top three elements
  +         Add the top two elements
   1}       Push a 1 to the bottom of the stack
     :nau   Print the top number with a trailing newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg), 10 bytes

```
01{:. ,:"+
```

Endlessly outputs numbers separated by spaces

## How it works

```
0    Pushes 0
1    Pushes 1
{    Begins an endless while loop
:.   Outputs the top item of the stack
 ,   Outputs a space
:"   Duplicates the top item of the stack and puts it at the bottom
+    Adds the top two numbers of the stack
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fwLDaSk9Bx0pJ@/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## x86 Machine Code (ELF format) - 484 bytes

This program will calculate fibonacci digits until there is no memory left, so you might want to process the output to get Nth one you are looking for.

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000  7F 45 4C 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .ELF............
00000010  02 00 03 00 01 00 00 00 C0 80 04 08 34 00 00 00  ........Ŕ€..4...
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 34 00 20 00 02 00 28 00  ........4. ...(.
00000030  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 04 08  .............€..
00000040  00 00 00 00 E4 01 00 00 00 10 00 00 05 00 00 00  ....ä...........
00000050  00 10 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 04 08  ................
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 06 00 00 00  ................
00000070  00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000080  51 B9 00 90 04 08 88 01 31 C0 BA 01 00 00 00 EB  Qą......1Ŕş....ë
00000090  03 51 89 C1 31 C0 89 C3 43 B0 04 CD 80 31 C0 99  .Q‰Á1Ŕ‰ĂC°.Í€1Ŕ™
000000A0  42 59 C3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  BYĂ.............
000000B0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000C0  31 C0 99 42 B9 03 90 04 08 C6 41 01 0A C6 41 02  1Ŕ™Bą....ĆA..ĆA.
000000D0  01 C6 41 03 01 3A 71 03 0F 84 FF 00 00 00 3A 71  .ĆA..:q..„˙...:q
000000E0  03 74 26 80 41 03 05 0F B6 41 03 6B C0 08 00 41  .t&€A...¶A.kŔ..A
000000F0  04 8A 41 04 E8 87 FF FF FF 80 69 04 30 C6 41 03  .ŠA.č‡˙˙˙€i.0ĆA.
00000100  01 83 E9 03 3A 71 03 75 DA 8A 41 04 E8 6F FF FF  ..é.:q.uÚŠA.čo˙˙
00000110  FF 3A 71 06 0F 84 BA 00 00 00 0F B6 41 05 88 41  ˙:q..„ş....¶A..A
00000120  06 0F B6 41 07 88 41 05 0F B6 41 07 00 41 06 C6  ..¶A..A..¶A..A.Ć
00000130  41 07 00 3A 71 06 0F 84 88 00 00 00 C6 41 07 01  A..:q..„....ĆA..
00000140  FE 49 06 3A 71 06 0F 84 78 00 00 00 C6 41 07 02  ţI.:q..„x...ĆA..
00000150  FE 49 06 3A 71 06 0F 84 68 00 00 00 C6 41 07 03  ţI.:q..„h...ĆA..
00000160  FE 49 06 3A 71 06 0F 84 58 00 00 00 C6 41 07 04  ţI.:q..„X...ĆA..
00000170  FE 49 06 3A 71 06 74 4C C6 41 07 05 FE 49 06 3A  ţI.:q.tLĆA..ţI.:
00000180  71 06 74 40 C6 41 07 06 FE 49 06 3A 71 06 74 34  q.t@ĆA..ţI.:q.t4
00000190  C6 41 07 07 FE 49 06 3A 71 06 74 28 C6 41 07 08  ĆA..ţI.:q.t(ĆA..
000001A0  FE 49 06 3A 71 06 74 1C C6 41 07 09 FE 49 06 3A  ţI.:q.t.ĆA..ţI.:
000001B0  71 06 74 10 FE 41 08 FE 41 09 FE 49 06 0F B6 41  q.t.ţA.ţA.ţI..¶A
000001C0  06 88 41 07 C6 41 06 01 83 C1 03 3A 71 06 0F 85  ..A.ĆA...Á.:q..…
000001D0  46 FF FF FF 3A 71 03 0F 85 01 FF FF FF B3 00 31  F˙˙˙:q..….˙˙˙ł.1
000001E0  C0 40 CD 80                                      Ŕ@Í€
```

Comment: no explanation?

Comment: @qwr Considering I have been 15 when this post has been made, I'm afraid that I would have to put as much effort into reverse engineering it as everyone else :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 7 bytes

```
12K+:N!
```

Byte knocked off courtesy of JoKing

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39DIW9vKT/H/fwA)

**9 bytes**

```
01T2K+:Nt
```

Outputs forever with newlines

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/38AwxMhb28qv5P9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## JVM Byte Code, 79 bytes

The byte count given is for a complete class file that defines a class `Code` containing single static method `Code` which implement Fibonacci. A hex dump of the file is given below.

```
0000000: cafe babe 0003 002d 0004 0100 0428 4929  .......-.....(I)
0000010: 4901 0004 436f 6465 0700 0200 2000 0300  I...Code.... ...
0000020: 0000 0000 0000 0100 0800 0200 0100 0100  ................
0000030: 0200 0000 1800 0400 0100 0000 0c03 045a  ...............Z
0000040: 6084 00ff 1a9d fffa ac00 0000 0000 00    `..............
```

A helper class is required to invoke the function.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            System.out.println(Code.Code(i));
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBfT8IwFMXf9ynOG1sIS7eVyQR9MZrw5AM@SUzs/hRrYCNbIRDDZ5@3bUDUm@y0ze759fTmovvo@8OhxKjFbDZ4fH4a4B4PTVmFxVp0HTzm6haFkBVykVegY0ISl2bHwSLGwHg8Ac/iDAhdjaz688AhIkLwjEXOw5NUIuXpGOzGuGMS@miXkGBOThuCyvAcIiYEs00/Yu@enBHuaOSc4lIOkRhEfHZH1sgvRksszOP4WPxDvDoEJ0TKJvRuJiUikZWQUgqI4ncyygC8/wlBA/a8QuirYb9UnQ4/xV54buLmjC/PuLe7fK0KdFpoWvaNKrERqvYXulX1avkG0a66wPWakk3rq1pD4Q5sSsuMhkrrcHjVZGpx7HS1CZudDreE0uvat@M24qsgmF66T57Tk41uYhZXiY1gVDf7qlXyaH/0/Tc)

---

The disassembly of the class file with `javap -c` shows actual byte code implementation of Fibonacci. This requires only 11 bytes, the rest of the 79 bytes in the class file are various header tables that can't be omitted.

```
class Code {
  static int Code(int);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: iconst_1
       2: dup_x1
       3: iadd
       4: iinc          0, -1
       7: iload_0
       8: ifgt          2
      11: ireturn
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
A(Z1)#HA(H+HG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/31EjylBT2cNRw0Pbw/3/fwA)

#### Explanation

```
A(Z1)#HA(H+HG

 (Z1)           : The tuple (0, 1)
A               : Assign the first value of the tuple to G and the second to H
     #          : Loop until error statement
      H         : Print H
        (H+HG   : The tuple (H, H + G)
       A        : Assign the first value of the tuple to G and the second to H
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ral](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ral), 27 bytes

```
11=,1*:0*+1=0=1/-:1:+:+?0*.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFBbsMgELz7Fav0ABjsgCr1QEujHnNKVPVmWRWxsYJkO8hO0lZV3@5C4sjOZbXMzA7D4n6O@0P7ODzAG7zrGmx7NJ3rjK9QHTr4WG@itap1syu19CS2rTsdMSHRZkThLF0XmDOJSlNBd2pxQWQEBbOsZ43KiotT4b1DqS4d4oImchkrlq4@Uc44y3L2@xeBm2z7VDtn2jI4w/YWok/dwWHifXowdW@AR/C1t7UB@1Kb8W6wrFSWClZkNg/HCsrrrUg6HNKW/glXXClEA7rFhG7xHE5GOLmHJZJaeejZYX0tE7f0HNsFls0Uu5kinqabTOce1WEzzfiYmVLdlEEXmoliIdn6LlWK5AbfB12hsArQ42yAfffKpVWN/sac@eRR@K/FYjEIoZiIJY@pUFyJZSKFpJKueJwOnifD0z8)

Answer (score 1):

### Go <s>114</s> <s>113</s> 106 chars

I'm sure this can be improved but I'd like to share my approach using the [closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) to calculate Fibonacci numbers.

```
package main
import(."fmt"
."math")
func main(){for i:=0.0;i<31;i++{Printf("%.0f\n",Pow(Phi,i)/Sqrt(5));}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 16 bytes

```
"1,"◙01W;a+;◙',◙
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/1/JUEfp0fSZBobh1ona1kCWug6Q@P8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## GAS x86-64 for Linux (Machine code), <s>76</s> 68 bytes

#### Loop-free, because I thought it would be a fun idea. GCC 10.1.

Note/warning: for this to work, you have to turn off DEP and PIE (ASLR). See compilation instructions below.

Look, ma! No loops! Byte count is for the assembled opcodes of `func` + `e` + `f`. Works on 32 bit input. Sure, you'll eventually run out of stack space, but the number will overflow before then. Obviously, a loop would have been much smaller (and easier) to write.

How it works:

1. Copy payload code to stack-relative space (No modification of `%rsp`)
2. Jump to copy destination's start.
3. Payload calculates the Fibonacci number in `%rax` and self-unwinds without ever looping
4. When it's done, return to caller of func

#### Full testing program:

```
// 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55
.global main

message: .asciz "%d"
main:
    mov $N, %rdi
    call func
    mov %eax, %esi
    mov $message, %rdi
    xor %eax, %eax
    call printf
    xor %eax, %eax
    ret

func:
    // We'll take %rdi, but we'll slice it to 32 bits
    // %edi is arg, r8d is our counter.
    mov %edi, %r8d
    // Make 2 copies for arithmetic
    mov %r8d, %eax
    // Set up stack offset
    // N * 32, need 64 bits to work with %rsp
    imul $(eof - e), %eax
    neg %rax
    mov %rsp, %r9
    lea (%rax, %r9), %r9
    // Initialize for Fibonacci
    xor %ebx, %ebx
    xor %eax, %eax
    inc %eax

    // Copy initial payload:
    // Because PIE is turned off, we can use 32-bit addressing for local
    // Stack still seems to be in 64-land, however
    mov $e, %esi
    mov %r9, %rdi
    mov $(eof - e), %ecx
    rep movsb

    // Go to stack offset
    jmp *%r9

e:
    // The payload:
    dec %r8d
    jg f
    ret
f:
    // Do actual Fibonacci stuff
    lea (%ebx, %eax), %edx
    mov %eax, %ebx
    mov %edx, %eax
    // Self-replicate
    mov %r9, %rsi
    mov $(eof - e), %cl
    rep movsb
eof:
```

I decided on 32-bit input because the stack is not all valid for 64 bits, so we'd run out anyway. It overflows after a we get high enough input, but that's expected.

#### Compilation:

```
# Prints 55
# Replace 10 with the input number (1-indexed):
gcc -no-pie -z execstack execstack_fibonacci.sx -DN=10 -g
```

- The `-z execstack` tells the linker to turn off DEP for this program. (Allow the stack to be executable)
- The `-no-pie` turns off ASLR.
- The `-DN10` is just easy input control.
- The `-g` is for debugging control. Turn it off if you want.

Note: this will *NOT* work in MinGW because the DEP policy is managed by the OS on Windows. In fact, `-z` isn't even recognized by MinGW's `ld`.

#### Hex dump:

```
funcs='func e f'
for el in $funcs; do
    echo 'Dump $el'
    gdb -batch -ex "disas/r $el" ./a.out | sed '/^$/d'
done
echo -n "payload size:"
gdb -batch -ex "print eof - e" ./a.out
```

Comment: You may be able to save quite a few bytes here, as there are a lot of unnecessary `REX` prefixes, and there isn't nearly enough `push`/`pop` abuse.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 24 bytes - recursive version, 33 bytes - usage of Binet's formula, 46 bytes - continuous approximation with the "phi" itself

Usage of ["Binet's formula"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) and a bitwise "OR" operator to round the result. Originally in the ["Binet's formula"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) you have to subtract the so-called "smaller phi to the n-th power". "Smaller phi" (-0.618...) is inside the (-1;1) interval, so it gets closer to 0 with each positive power - that's why we can leave it, and just round the meaningful part. Function itself is an anonymous one, declared with the arrow function declaration.

```
n=>(((5**.5/2+.5)**n)/5**.5)+.5|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcdLCoAgEADQdZ7C5YySReCq7C5RGoY4UdKmOrt9Vo@3DMewj5tfUxlpsjk7E00PAFoIpatGKo1CRKz@49urZo42CDZxzw2v25eON59S4smKkeJOwapAMzjwiOzO@QE)

Recursive version - arrow function declaration. Check whether n is less than 3, if so return 1, else do it again (at least) 2 more  times, but with an argument of value n-1 and n-2:

```
f=n=>n<3?1:f(n-1)+f(n-2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcVLCoAgEADQdZ7CpYMUfXaldRYxDUNmIqVNdHart3m7uUyyZzhyjbS6UrxGPaMalm70AusO5F8PzNMposs8cM3b6Uvx/l9KuFllCRNF10TahBcBgD2lvA)

Continuous approximation. Ni * phi = Ni+1.

**WARNING - RUNNING THIS CODE WILL END UP AS AN INFINITE AMOUNT OF ALERTS (next after clicking "ok")**

```js
f=n=>{l=n/2+5**.5/2*n+.5|0;alert(l);f(l)};f(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 32 bytes

```
i1
1<esc>qqkyjGp:s:\n:+
C<C-r>=<C-r>"
<esc>@qq@q
```

[(don't)Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9OQy9AmtTjZrrAwuzLLvcCq2Comz0qby9nGWbfIzhZMKnGBVTgUFjoU/v//X7cMAA)

Prints the sequence forever.

Output is not visible on TIO, so here's the first 99 iterations: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9OQy9AmtTjZrrAwuzLLvcCq2Comz0qby9nGWbfIzhZMKnFBVFhaOhT@//9ftwwA)

Last accurate value is \$7540113804746346429\$ after which it exceeds the integer limit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Duocentehexaquinquagesimal](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Duocentehexaquinquagesimal), 5 bytes

```
±∊YO$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFhiYxPzqGGRXbx1cWqKgm6mgrphsXWcNVDIWl0hXsHILq80x7qkqDQPqDRVQbdY11Ah3jo1OSNfQTdPQR2oLOnQMuPDW5yP7stQsrPR1tXTiY5VetSw0Evdzg6isEY/v6BEP784MSkzFUopxNslWYOFk4oSM/PSSpOzESyFpP@mjxrmORzaFR71H2jBfwA) Link is to a version with output; this one just writes the sequence to memory. Outputs codepoints of the entire sequence. Stops eventually because of memory limitations.

Answer (score 1):

## [Branch](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/branch-lang/), 18 bytes

```
1XY[/x#^\yX^+Y10.]
```

Try it on the [online Branch interpreter](https://branch.hyper-neutrino.xyz/#WyIxWFlbL3gjXlxceVheK1kxMC5dIiwiIiwiIl0=)!

Outputs infinitely. Eventually starts producing garbage values because `long long int` overflows but that seems to be acceptable.

### Explanation

```
1                   Set the node's value to 1
 XY                 Set the X and Y registers to 1
   [             ]  While value is not 0 (this will always be true in this program)
    /x#             Move to the left child, set to the X register, and output as number
       ^\           Move to the parent and then right child (go to right sibling)
         yX         Set to the Y register, then set the X register to that value
           ^+Y      Move to root, sum the children (X + Y), and set the Y register
              10.   Place 10 and output as character; this also keeps the loop going
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
;=x=y 1W!Ox=y+x=x y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltc9pIEv4Mv2IgZZCESCTZV7UFCCrJ2inXOXbWTi4fbC6WhbBVK4ROEn7ZxPvXc909LxrxkrvcbaqM0MzTPd3P9HT3kLB/G4bfX8RpmKxm0agoZ/Hy5d24qY8k8U1tKCyfsmgNlMfpbW2ojBccM4vmcRqxJGHJMr2lj6Ya/Xj66T1zq9eLj@fMq17/8fqcHVSvR6dv2S/V6/kn5lbgo5MLDXv66USDfjp9//ri70ZhMgM/OuxP92@mmn19AcvyyfAuyJllVgI6CmxVKsZjdlDNnR5@xskUJsmjbwy/j0ZrGFyGMOgmYJLERGAN8@bs7IRA@DEhJwfom2bI@TsOAHnN1vsgWUWmeZlOzWaT/IBduZz65@3DsyPj@9B/9J@Y@7l1Bs/eo//Inr6bMNMecrAF6ChYMB/Fhs0m6M6CvIgMk31tNuK0ZPGw2YBRWsdm1nyVhjBCwiG8l4vMLrL00pv6Xx3beQYdjRjUER6eDg68eoXq44w93MVlVGRBGDUb8D2JDBgHcYObYbP2VXmVXs2vcvb1@XJqmIMXbZNMacRzZihrfdZ90TUZVyFHWzB6lcJwr8dHwM5GlBSRPvDMzQnvovB3Nl/mLF0tbqK8EPYwIy5m8W1cSq2wOrrj2soj/rSY67Aes4TlvZ7J@qzrdGEJtDQ2WR6VqzxlMjK4GAXHcN2G@yCPg5skklaAEcnyIcqNENaThrBv35g0LqS3kIj40jUFPfEW12PftWGPfDW8Zh2eNRGTAElnq8zALWWC0z6Dt02D@ckvuDZuxlW3W9nU7vJNA2HwQBnFQAlkCvgOlmVBUbLyLgJlQV4CWGyAJRnFDQ1N9EQaqx2gncbCp2vSRjcqMsh8DN0yXqZgNkasMwXTQslIscoyJNyUUSVHdPr1@APaNbJRhwzlLIU4hqyFkSss56x87KqjzQeOcAAz2AAzF5opg4ySHnfVQLvR1CBJlqFx4NiuiQ7isHKCHExXSRLkT7qj1f6ca9vzoassowWF/Cpdk6YlXFxCJIVtnh6@eXv9W@vk1zPNX13rTbxVrbeptlXT@@74YofGMspJZZDO2L9WgXxFtff6EvubS3D/33UVFcdbqCDhg7pwHfNMmTJfpbhBQ5F4rXJZGDJVUvxDZJdxyGj2ZjW/9A6mwg6@zx3KDsqAIoNTVc4NgIL/e0kya8u0Q4XHRiXrCuBMKAW8pPH1a7gRc/frfqLzGIoT1i7zVdSGEFTjGJEwPg8ggeBEGwOrXZGAfqLvovYQHV/eLJcJzNzUGdjpa@XWjxyyft4j3cybDTMTtDH9S22EoC2XSWLoptrMsaFA/A8mpxsmYxF@//rDqY2lmAcavB5fuo7jQDiBK/Aq34r4j@hLyfAx1GJU8xYZgDcbPzz63PddWdExwWFRxwd9evyxD4Cj45NDi80hNw4bKrTFepiFwyCzkyilBkDjSrZGnDM4d7vIWBfE0oSVDeuNEVMrAaV4RFwMoabEOKnyRrjI1naASIqnVQpBmuIpLlM8xGV4Z1jAzEYnhRyFWJ8gYw6kqOj0csg4htlxHuf4D3eXIz8AEmzgNt5GZQINm9EhLjvIEFaoWZyaQ00fNZ9ljjUMHibVWK7tkGvjbRmeNWz9MOdLadxTkZkqG95U1nK8mnlbzaAk/gmNFeYaMMg17K6fLbMoNbSF7XbepjoMVvkLXoZgt33POfiFxkXlNni5n4PpM3QK@iMICBubJ4BDYaY3XAOWlptnwCDr@dRn4HkApCnIBD20FhGJGiyfeXpDUNFYefIbeBI9Qo@EZ2nDz1ZtT6nrbmGe2ACebGw@rJLUedHgv3YHognjceTrLKu8IvJ7@5R6TgMzvClT/Hh8YFZd20aykaIX1HkZewUK6gG/TRjohL5CXxfylNmuoHICk3cUpELtrgIhKoK@A@LkChbOKhYw7PmtAknj@1mjjnU6dFXp9xE65T3kFfWyDWnW3kurAHsMeDOZPEi5Zv6qLOTuq5jgjRQ3qKcMoiwE2QgTHoaWtj28VW3Ud5vf@xANTTWTseTxPcfmkg4D3wBC4TCmSl966ZnbQzUMSvkQLZ3bq2gy5XfUZUKrZ9OzFDlC@NXfiE4t2rEPrtvLhaxqd7awsF78tvBgbfDA93UbC4strlmE8XUlJAAZ3qAy43ev4AaFoGG/T/oEUVSQ1jeaM1rWTv@rHxLzajsxez8U2tsu9E9is@YQ78tpzNO9HAraOes@67uKZcIC9S6cs74LZ8zVwd5PokeQHmtY30corTuQI46knIj2xo7g2jOpGbB84r@5fiBoklyBDpwSLJYY@I4N@V2UR92CpUvoUOOkjFP2EDwBb2y2hAtfGd1GOchkyzRKyzjAHh1O8pI9ROwuuI8AKBQhvGSLIF1B@Dy9xFH07gYZByqIiWKVlHgjp8VVwpOQvo6RS65RpsspyJp61Lcb6ew2RMFGNZRDl98gwdr4BF6nsySasevK7Gul5St@422PtkjlzBiV9fvy3SR4Q0AtzfRnlQdHFKxrhQ@TXi0v@vWsOGH64R/pxwBFB@IXrQ7jgAmrtWE0aDMtG6IOh0vKkuvxOoDYlg/VRuuCxnAoMbSWs@WALaJFmGGYpWx8Pfl/XRn/Ba6MpSutLb74whfhymQ3@3zVLSbj9ITVAJ5CeLKAtrbZWb0o92Tm0RUo8zpV@kNfttWGiS4pUomS//bfyIscpKlR8sPuQEfX2tx1rF9l3fr0T18TZG9b3RMQ16jdFVQqJAxqnPo1aS1NogQiej0lxk3@DO7xn5T0RrPmHdN7FyF2XO/aEarJT7zBvkbLO35l8LUOq6cXoM17RyouHrY6C/u1hvaCE72mdLhe8rxtJW/fVH2Ap6QPaPA/NERoGD5xK0LV/Kt2SO@NPPAQV@252CRRg8Djn0/SgxA9cRJg9Vk0DyBJgmeyw4xTmIxn9BNNEJZQprp7YRd7Thwx2Y47IipTNRC6QXFNXwRxis0qC/Lb0CallgXf7038MYhuj/gfJIZD1tSvcc/f/w0)

-1 byte: `W1;Ox` -> `W!Ox`

The "print infinitely" variant. (It will eventually overflow).

It is a simple add and swap loop.

Ungolfed:

```php
# init x and y to 1
; = x (= y 1)
# loop forever
# since OUTPUT evaluates to NULL, we
# can just invert the condition 
: WHILE !(OUTPUT x) {
    # Add and swap
    : = y + x (= x y)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>79</s> <s>70</s> <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```c
y;z;main(x){for(;printf("%i ",z=x+y);y=z)x=y;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///v9K6yjo3MTNPo0KzOi2/SMO6oCgzryRNQ0k1U0FJp8q2QrtS07rStkqzwrbSuvb/fwA)

Uses a for-loop instead of a while-loop just because I use it more and doing `while()` gives the same byte count.

Thanks to ceilingcat for golfing 9 bytes. Thanks to Jo King for golfing 23 bytes. Thanks to ceilingcat for golfing another byte.

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///v9I6NzEzT6NCszotv0jD2rqgKDOvJE1DSTVTQUmn0rZCt1JTs0LbttK69v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>46</strike> 44 bytes

```
lambda n,a=5**.5:((.5+a/2)**n-(.5-a/2)**n)/a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSFPJ9HWVEtLz9RKQ0PPVDtR30hTSytPF8jWhbI19RP//wcA)

Uses [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet%27s_formula) to derive the `nth` Fibonacci number.

***Very*** wrong answer from me misreading the question:

```python
g=lambda n:n+g(n-1)if n else n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P902JzE3KSVRIc8qTztdI0/XUDMzTSFPITWnOFUh7/9/AA)

Comment: The logic is right, but it does start to drift pretty quickly due to floating point errors.  I'm not sure if this is 100% Kosher.

Comment: Fair. It's probably fine [but it was not specified](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20528/what-is-our-consensus-on-floating-point-issues/20533#20533), so I guess we're in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

## [Mascarpone](https://github.com/catseye/Mascarpone), 45 bytes

```
v['1.]v*'b<^[v{^vv'b>'a<[ab]v*'b<^a'
.:!]v*:!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sTk4sKsjPS/3/vyxa3VAvtkxLPckmLrqsOq6sTD3JTj3RJjoxCSqaqM6lZ6UI5Fgp/v8PAA)

Outputs the numbers in unary, separated by newlines.

High-level explanation (go read [the language specification](https://github.com/catseye/Mascarpone) first):

I redefine the interpreter to have two symbols, `a` and `b`, which kind of act as variables. Each symbol's operation prints a certain amount of `1`s, so they kind of act as numbers in unary, and the operation corresponding to the string `ab` prints out the sum of `a` and `b`. At the start, `a` corresponds to 0 and `b` is 1. Each step, I simultaneously redefine `(a, b) = (b, a+b)` and then I output the new value of `a`.

Slightly less high-level explanation:

I will replace the newline with `N` because its only function is to help push a newline character — it doesn’t actually do anything special in terms of the logic of the program.

Due to the longness of the program, I’ll divide this explanation up into parts.

The beginning:

```
v['1.]v*'b<^
```

This changes the current interpreter so that the symbol `b` corresponds to the operation of outputting a single `1`. (`a` corresponds to a no-op by default, so it doesn’t have to be mentioned here).

The rest of the program:

I will use the notation `[x]` (where `x` can be any character) to mean “the operation the current interpreter associates with the symbol `x`’, since that’s a lot to type and I don’t have much margin space to write the explanation in.

```
[v{^vv'b>'a<[ab]v*'b<^a'N.:!]v*:!
[                         :!]v*:!  Loop forever:
 v{^                                 Hard to explain
    v                                Create a new interp,
         'a<                           where a is assoc with
     v'b>                                [b]
                  'b<                  and b is assoc with
            [ab]v*                       [ab] (i.e. [a], then [b])
                     ^               Set current interp := that interp
                      a              Now run the op corresponding to a
                       'N.             and print a trailing newline.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [flax](https://github.com/PyGamer0/flax), 3 bytes

```
1+ⁿ
```

Port of the Jelly answer. Takes input from stdin. Works similarly to the Jelly answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [HOPS](https://akc.is/hops/), 10 bytes

```
seq(x+x^2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kI7-geG20kq5uQVFqsq2RgVLsgqWlJWm6FquKUws1KrQr4ow0IQJQ8QVQGgA)

---

## [HOPS](https://akc.is/hops/), 11 bytes

```
1/(1-x-x^2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kI7-geG20kq5uQVFqsq2RgVLsgqWlJWm6FqsN9TUMdSt0K-KMNCEiUIkFUBoA)

The generating function of the Fibonacci sequence is \$1/(1-x-x^2)\$. In HOPS, `seq(f)` means `1/(1-f)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubestack](https://github.com/tobyck/cubestack), 22 bytes

```
M R' M' z u2 b u2 R z'
```

Outputs forever in the [offline version](https://github.com/tobyck/cubestack#usage) and in the online version it outputs as many as it can in 5 seconds.

[Try it Online!](https://cubestack.surge.sh?TSBSJyBNJyB6IHUyIGIgdTIgUiB6Jw%3D%3D&)

Explanation:

```
M R' M'                 # Push 1 to the stack
        z               # Open an (infinite) while loop
          u2 b          # Without popping, print
               u2 R     # Without popping, add
                    z'  # Close while loop
```

Answer (score 1):

### Regex  (ECMAScript<sup><sup>[RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine/)</sup></sup> / Perl / PCRE / Raku), 8 bytes

```
^(xx?)*$
```

Takes its input in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length represents the number. Returns its output as the number of ways the regex can match. (The rabbit emoji indicates this output method. It can yield outputs bigger than the input, and is really good at multiplying.)

[Try it on replit.com](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/regex-Fibonacci-sequencehttps://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/regex-Fibonacci-sequence) (RegexMathEngine)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/LTsMwELz3K1bWqvKSR5MiLnVelcqVEzdarBK1koVpgx2kQBKOfACfyI@kTkDistqdnd2ZqQ5G3wwv74BGQKvP5V4DLoQb02Szvl9n/ex4NhxtGokkE9SCOrqJ2sqoUw1se2Kih0KnttKq5ixgvn17srU7kX4Q@zEdXkdS/o9GDqcVShLjL@sU96bQyZLaQj/Eu9TVaCf6GcCkrP4AVEk6EVznedRi6SwBZw1rUFH6ueB5x/MVGuJ563lY9rR9TqT8yDrk@dSERGM0O59P7ifzLlks4DcNqpDBz9c3sBBLR@zcqu@lvL3bSDk88qbJ6QqHIQqulxc) - Perl v5.28.2
[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU-7TsMwFBVrv8Kyripf8mhSFlTnVamsTGxtsUrUSBamDXEqBZIw8gGsLB2KxDcx8iU4SSUW-5zjc33P-Tzl20Idfy7g6YVAwUmt9ulGEZhwQ8NgMb-bR-0o2xcMdOjxIOJYE5kZhnVeyF1J6GpHeUsSFepcyZJRh9r68KBLMyJsx7d93D53pvhf9YyOMxDIu7-02bgpEhVMsU7U0l-H5vTWvB0R0m-WZwFkEPYGgywLa0hNJMJoRSuQGL5NWNyweAYFsri2LEhbXD0GQrxGDbC4By5iV02Px336Prxp5nMytAHpUvL7_kGoC6kxNuapbYW4uV0I8XUoM-f6-55VVYyXMNDj-Tp5ztV0wH8) - Perl v5.36+
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVThbpswEP6fp7iytTGBVKGRpglCo67rtB9ZO0WptCnNEHUMsUoMMrCk7fp3D7BH3IMsO@OQ0nUbSsCc77777rszNMu6MaWbF1zQpJwzGGRUssPFcYsuQglBNp2BD2PjzWp1c90vP9/efposXq0WZPOFrNdDs/NyY/65Z9jQyfwgsxyv9YibF3OeKuCmSXIRP7XxFK0sXD73O25xUUCGyyJgUqaS0FTkBVREO0uW52HMzHvM47oUHWAwgK1VLSs7E/PEA8mKUgpwvIdWKXIeCzaHJBWxvoUiXzHpVdmWtwENkyQtC6J0qV@C6ySlN9ChJtxrd8vawfYQtooNuSDo0AK8sikWkTBBMrPrzPyeB5qQLg0y6htk6Boeriw/0w/DJMNT/O@ZaC8Rsn8UFJCqYIUf46LCbgJxkZWFCpcMOpJ50NQIRckKqaMly8uk0GulZhTlrLABi0OWcbHQO@lXRotUTvsznQpRfdBKpMuMJwxlOaQBJiemDR9Px2fB24vJyWgE3/Tb5eTdaxsOdGa9qFP1TI3JIyB7kpm1flHV4ohgWehtg6GAKo4SQqRUhcP@3IX9/ErgsDUwdZ4tcLNjSPuxl3o7QjyiirxTilYixqxIuGBEzxAXttbT9NDHqVtZccYw0UPQsEg5qZxqGVAH4diQpTlu652Iizlpd9tbXuoSjhISffb8Zv9cVyjj8C@4YFX@FiARF5M/YunmqnSCrfTbVDiWM/Nw/peoC8ltaK/bihiWkuPmzG/E74TgvlCzNfCF44Fl8WbFdafuTEBSKglpX4m2lmYrH1VC41Hj6mbAz@8/ACdXHxBk10ipZ0lNYD1PbM0okcyG88vRyAZkzHFEqt92CG3om94zPhpl0IODgxoRJa1m72w8vhgH5xcfTian780nkbtjU1M2ztR8GU/xWZKz/4dta6s/L1FS5ot/VNmo/qGl79VMu3oYJWNYi7n7imzPZ@th0@v2j37RKAnjfNNNlFi/AQ) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrTuNGFP6fpzh4W5hJnG0S1BWKMYgNkUDahVU2qNtlqWXscTJaZ2zZ4w1Q8bcP0EfsgzQ9c3FiSKRa4Mycy3fux1Ged2dRtHoTs4QLBp9Gk/EgGF2fj4Obq8tp8Nvl@fQCjlpvuIjSKmZwnEcFG7ydn7SieVhAkN/egQ8T5/1y@f3@sPr98fHLdP5uOSerP8jDwylt/7Sir3mOC@3cD/JO32sAl7LgYqaQNzSeIZWFi5MtuZMWFxJyPMqAFUVWkCgTpQTtVXvByjKcMQp/ljIeDiOUgONjsGR11HQm4tSDgsmqEND3nrcw1T3KYubCfZalkPlJmJYKVpuxcLeDX9/deS3AhydAdIKCGbMYgZUiBoeYDN@MLs4mR21qmS6U/IllCVk7/ktNachTSrUV9ZAMTk0QUVZJGMI6UKrCc7QaaA@G4LwKXis7Dmo534RD1/lI0qqcm0jWSWk9typR8plgMaSZmJlXKMolKzydsMVjEIVpim7Y2O0tuE@z6Du0Ixd@ZDyGdhzKEHOnkqSO4PtAFKdN9zcY1GJ3OuvK9GxlFiEXBAG0g/ktNkLKBMlpt3/n9zwTgukOyCPfIadDx8NTx8/Nj0PJ6Qj/9yjSK0Q8HAQSi4q6Cn6GBw3dBOIir6RS14FhCaFdsPq@CGU0D3Qs7c3ZoBWsrFLpmhJ4drA@X34da0qSlAyZGC@GMJPzFwLt7AeLJGrZSuCA1fYXOU8ZsU3x@dN0QvPobRSgs4S6FuPreHIdTMeTj5dXZ9PxeU0ef5mOr87VfV/7ZH@tJz266eC9AhvQ5r45Dfpt5Rqh@1vZCPAeShYkRbYI8lBKVghSYJdf3Xz4YAGaOji6kj1ITGJ98nfxLSzZQsEI1i1YQ7iNvnR39dlrAGMq5QveBOn2qdcQilku/1eoYFFVlDwTOwW12SQrQG@Xp3Xn4sZIcQUTM8hcuKb3qFd3vC4PqogepieUGSdaoC4/1l/0XcizEtmGgys9JgfdA2tUPaKvcosye36zz4dDoYinO3Cho@U70Ke4MERvg2V2rTIn2NLcbkW/07/zcNksMBOkdOHg4UA5hgkqkXnnN/TXSeC@UDN47Iu@B50Ob0ZcN@UTBXRKGSEH3wSGhKlDad2fCXF@juGfv/4G/LRwZJkVgo41rJlZUkP5srt0YzYnCp3mOBD6b9PTeLZlpN6Wcwb3uAf7@9bGnm@nbjK5ngRX1x/PpqML@kJRt19jvOqNIYuKvbLB8KuzpbvZ/ri/bcQ7Nrl6nlub967BSgrGyCa@7YE2Aus7bW5Ew8SdsV7YJhL8dKx63cPBv1GShrNy1U21TvfoPw) - PCRE2 v10.33
[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVZLb9tGED4W0K8YM621K1GpZKOBIZo2HFmADSR2oMhoGkUlaHIpLUItCXIZPwJf8wN67aWHFuglP6g99m_00tmHJNoSUMKi9jHzzeubkX_9GuVpVapPMIuirxOnk-ZRwfY6B870r9GzmCVcMHgzGA33gsHl6TC4ujgfBz-en47P4KDxjIsorWIGh1rp-fyoEc3DAoJ8MgUfRs7Lm5uP1_vVT3d378bzFzdz8kclk87Bnz-T29tj2vrWbP_-5l_6VNJxoZX7Qd7ueTUzpSy4mCk76zOe4SkLF0cbckcNLiTkuJQBK4qsIFEmSgnax9aClWU4YxQ-lzLu9yOUgMNDsMdqqc-ZiFMPCiarQkDPe9jAVPsoi5kL11mWQuYnYVoqWG3Gwk32fngx9RqAD0-A6HQFM2YxAitFDA4x-b4anJ2MDlrUXrpQ8nuWJWTl-PfLk5o8pVRbUQ_J4NgEEWWVhD6sAqUqPEergfagD86T4LWy46CW80E4dJWPBLkyN5GsktJ4aFSi5DPBYkgzMTOvUJQ3rPB0whZ3QRSmKbphY7e74DrNoo_Qilz4lPEYWnEoQ8ydSpJagu8DUTcturvGoBa73V5Vpmsrswi5IAigHcwnSISUCZLTTm_qdz0TgmEH5JHvkOO-4-Gq7efmy6HkeICfHYrnFSLu7wUSi4q6Cn6GCw1dB-Iir6RS14FhCaFVsOV-EcpoHuhYWuu1QStYWaXSNSXwbJu9PX8_1CdJUjK8xHgxhJmcPxJoZZ9YJFHLVgLbbWl_kfOUEUuKt2_GI5pHz6MAnSXUtRjvh6PLYDwcvT6_OBkPT5fHw3fj4cWp2u9qn-y39aRL1wzeKZCANvf1btBvK1cL3d_IRoD7ULIgKbJFkIdSskKQAll-cfXqlQWo62DrSnYrMYnLlb_t3sKSDRSMYEXBJYRb46W7jWdPAYyplC94HaTTo15NKGa5_F-hgkVVUfJMbBXUZpOsAD1d7lfMxYmR4kAmppG5cA33qLdkvC4PqogupieUGSdaYFl-rL_ouZBnJV6bGxzwMWl2mtaoekRP5RZldvw6z_t9oQ6Pt-BCW8u3oUdxYIjuGsvMWmVOsBuzm4heuzf1cNgsMBOkdKF521SOYYJKvJz6Nf1VErgvVA8e-qLnQbvN6xEvSXlPAZ1SRkjzg8CQMHUorfmZEOe7GP758gvgTwvHKzNC0LGaNdNLqikfs0sTs95R6DTHhtB_a07j2paRehvOGdzDLuzuWhs7vu260ehyFFxcvj4ZD87oI0VNv1p7LSeGLCr2xAbDX50N3fX0x_ltI94yydXz0Fi_tzVWUjBG1vFtNrQRWO1pfSKaS5wZq4FtIsGfDvM_wG-_dzv7e2b9Hw) - PCRE2 v10.40+
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoFKkYKugb6Nim5aZl1mcYadvrVCcWKmgraFeoV6hEq@pl5tYkpyhoVKkY5VaoamQll@kEGdkbM0FVf8/TqOiwl5TS@X/fwA) - Raku

This uses the same technique as my [Perl answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223243/17216) – it counts [how many distinct partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Symbolic_method) \$n\$ has as a sum of the numbers \$1\$ and \$2\$. But the focus here is on variations possible in the regex, treating the logic behind invoking it as a black box – as the language this answer is written in.

That block box doesn't just count the number of overlapping substrings that match (which would just be 1 with this regex, since it's anchored on both sides) but the number of ways in which different choices can lead to a full match (where choices are available, that is – in atomic constructs, the element of choice is eliminated). The counting of this is implemented by forcing the regex engine to backtrack at the end of any complete successful match (by turning it into a failed match), incrementing a counter every time that is done.

One interesting way to modify the Fibonacci sequence regex is to change its indexing. Getting the sequence to start one earlier, yielding \$0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8...\$, is trivial, but the others are interesting, and starting 4 later is where it begins to get difficult (and I'm sure it can be golfed better than I have so far). At certain point, it should become optimal to emulate `(xx?)*` in the extra space that is missing, but I haven't worked out how to do that yet.

2 earlier - [**13 bytes** - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrTttIFP6fpzi4XZhJnG5CtQjFMYgNkUBqoUqDtluaWsYeJ6M6Y8seN4GWv/sA@4j7IMueuSQxJNJa4MzlnO/cvnMc5Xl7GkVPr2KWcMHgw2A0PAwG1@fD4Obqchz8cXk@voDjxisuorSKGfTzqGCHb2YnjWgWFhDktxPwYeT8vlh8u3tb/Xl//2k8O1rMyNPX5ZIsl6e0@frn19dP9KWA40Iz94O81fVq6KUsuJgq@M0Zz/CUhfOTLbmTBhcSclzKgBVFVpAoE6UE7VpzzsoynDIKP0oZ93oRSkC/D/ZYLfU5E3HqQcFkVQjoeo9bmGofZTFz4S7LUsj8JExLBavNWLjbw9@OJl4D8OEJEJ2lYMosRmCliMEhJs03g4uz0XGT2ksXSv7AsoSsHf91dVKTp5RqK@ohGZyaIKKsktCDdaBUhedoNdAe9MB5EbxWdhzUcr4Ih67zkaRVOTORrJPSeGxUouRTwWJIMzE1r1CUC1Z4OmHz@yAK0xTdsLHbXXCXZtE3aEYufM94DM04lCHmTiVJLcH3gaibJt3fYFCL3WqtK9OxlZmHXBAE0A7mt0iElAmS03Z34nc8E4JhB@SR75DTnuPhquXn5seh5HSA/3sUzytEfHsYSCwq6ir4KS40dB2Ii7ySSl0HhiWEZsFW@3koo1mgY2lu1gatYGWVSteUwLPd9fHy81CfJEnJ8BLjxRCmcvZMoJl9Z5FELVsJ7LKV/XnOU0YsKT5@GI9oHr2JAnSWUNdifB6OroPxcPT@8upsPDxfHQ8/jYdX52q/r32yv9aTDt0weK9AAtrc17tBv61cLXR/KxsB7kPJgqTI5kEeSskKQQpk@dXNu3cWoK6DrSvZUmISVyt/172FJVsoGMGagisIt8ZLdxfPXgIYUymf8zpIu0u9mlDMcvm/QgWLqqLkmdgpqM0mWQF6ujysmYsTI8U5TEwjc@Ea7lFvxXhdHlQRHUxPKDNOtMCq/Fh/0XUhz0q8Njc412Ny0D6wRtUjuiq3KLPn13ne6wl1eLoDF1pavgVdigNDdDZYZtYqc4ItzO5WdFvdiYfDZo6ZIKULB8sD5RgmqMTLiV/TXyeB@0L1YN8XXQ9aLV6PeEXKBwrolDJCDr4IDAlTh9Kanwlxfonhn7/@Bvy0cLwyIwQdq1kzvaSa8jm7NDHrHYVOc2wI/bfhNK5tGam35ZzB7Xdgf9/a2PNt141G16Pg6vr92XhwQZ8pavrV2ms1MWRRsRc2GH51tnQ30x/nt414xyRXz2Nj897VWEnBGNnEt93QRmC9p/WJaC5xZqwHtokEPx1Pnfbh0b9RkobT8qmdap328X8): `^xx(xx?)*$|^$`
1 earlier  -  [**9 bytes** - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrbtpIFP7PU5y4u8kMmC5QtYpwHJQlSInUJhUl2m7TrOXYYxjVjC17XEiq/O0D7CPugyx75gI4AWmtxMycy3fux1Get6dRtHoVs4QLBh@H41EvGF6fj4Kbq8tJ8Mfl@eQCjhuvuIjSKmZwkkcF672enTaiWVhAkN/egQ9j5/fF4tv9m@rPh4fPk9m7xYys/lqS5XJAm7@s6Eum40Iz94O81fVqyKUsuJgq6C2NZ0hl4fx0R@60wYWEHI8yYEWRFSTKRClBu9Wcs7IMp4zCj1LG/X6EEnByApasjprORJx6UDBZFQK63tMOprpHWcxcuM@yFDI/CdNSwWozFu629/bdndcAfHgCRGcomDKLEVgpYnCISfHN8OJsfNyklulCyR9ZlpCN47@tKTV5Sqm2oh6SwcAEEWWVhD5sAqUqPEergfagD86L4LWy46CW81U4dJOPJK3KmYlkk5TGU6MSJZ8KFkOaial5haJcsMLTCZs/BFGYpuiGjd3egvs0i75BM3Lhe8ZjaMahDDF3KknqCL4PRHGa9HCLQS12q7WpTMdWZh5yQRBAO5jfYiOkTJCctrt3fsczIZjugDzyHTLoOx6eWn5ufhxKBkP8P6BIrxDxTS@QWFTUVfBTPGjoOhAXeSWVug4MSwjNgq3v81BGs0DH0tyeDVrByiqVrimBZyfr0@WXkaYkScmQifFiCFM5eybQzL6zSKKWrQRO2Nr@POcpI7YpPn2cjGkevY4CdJZQ12J8GY2vg8lo/OHy6mwyOl@TR58no6tzdT/UPtlf60mHbjv4oMAGtLmvT4N@W7la6P5ONgK8h5IFSZHNgzyUkhWCFNjlVzfv31uAug6OrmRLiUlcn/x9fAtLdlAwgk0LriHcWl@6@/rsJYAxlfI5r4O0u9SrCcUsl/8rVLCoKkqeib2C2mySFaC3y@Omc3FjpLiDiRlkLlzTe9Rbd7wuD6qIDqYnlBknWmBdfqy/6LqQZyWyDQd3ekyO2kfWqHpEV@UWZQ78ep/3@0IRB3twoaXlW9CluDBEZ4tldq0yJ9jC3G5Ft9W983DZzDETpHThaHmkHMMElci882v6myRwX6gZPPFF14NWi9cjXjflIwV0ShkhR18FhoSpQ2ndnwlxfo3hn59/A35aOLLMCkHHatbMLKmhfN5dujHrE4VOcxwI/bftaTzbMlJvxzmDe9KBw0Nr48C3UzceX4@Dq@sPZ5PhBX2mqNuvNl7rjSGLir2wwfCrs6O73f64v23Eeza5ep4a2/e@wUoKxsg2vt2BNgKbO61vRMPEnbFZ2CYS/HSsOu3e23@jJA2n5aqdap328X8): `^x(xx?)*$`
original  -  [**8 bytes** - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrbtpIFP7PU5y4u8kMmC7Q3SrCOCibICVSm1SUaLtNWcuxxzCqGVv2uCSp8rcPsI@4D7LsmQvgBKS1EjNzLt@5H0d53p5F0epVzBIuGHw4G496wdn1@Si4ubqcBH9cnk8u4LjxiosorWIGgzwqWO/1/KQRzcMCgvx2Cj6Mnd@Xy693b6o/Hx4@TeZvl3Oy@ovc3w9p86cVfclzXGjmfpC3ul4NuJQFFzOFvKXxDKksXJzsyJ00uJCQ41EGrCiygkSZKCVor5oLVpbhjFH4Xsq4349QAgYDsGR11HQm4tSDgsmqEND1nnYw1T3KYubCXZalkPlJmJYKVpuxcLe9395OvQbgwxMgOkHBjFmMwEoRg0NMhm/OLk7Hx01qmS6U/JFlCdk4/suaUpOnlGor6iEZDE0QUVZJ6MMmUKrCc7QaaA/64LwIXis7Dmo5X4RDN/lI0qqcm0g2SWk8NSpR8plgMaSZmJlXKMolKzydsMVDEIVpim7Y2O0tuEuz6Cs0Ixe@ZTyGZhzKEHOnkqSO4PtAFKdJD7cY1GK3WpvKdGxlFiEXBAG0g/ktNkLKBMlpuzv1O54JwXQH5JHvkGHf8fDU8nPz41AyPMP/A4r0ChHf9AKJRUVdBT/Dg4auA3GRV1Kp68CwhNAs2Pq@CGU0D3Qsze3ZoBWsrFLpmhJ4drA@Xn4eaUqSlAyZGC@GMJPzZwLN7BuLJGrZSuCAre0vcp4yYpvi44fJmObR6yhAZwl1Lcbn0fg6mIzG7y@vTiej8zV59GkyujpX90Ptk/21nnTotoMPCmxAm/v6NOi3lauF7u9kI8B7KFmQFNkiyEMpWSFIgV1@dfPunQWo6@DoSnYvMYnrk7@Pb2HJDgpGsGnBNYRb60t3X5@9BDCmUr7gdZB2l3o1oZjl8n@FChZVRckzsVdQm02yAvR2edx0Lm6MFFcwMYPMhWt6j3rrjtflQRXRwfSEMuNEC6zLj/UXXRfyrES24eBKj8lR@8gaVY/oqtyizIFf7/N@XyjicA8utLR8C7oUF4bobLHMrlXmBFua263otrpTD5fNAjNBSheO7o@UY5igEplTv6a/SQL3hZrBgS@6HrRavB7xuikfKaBTygg5@iIwJEwdSuv@TIjzcwz//Pgb8NPCkWVWCDpWs2ZmSQ3l8@7SjVmfKHSa40Dov21P49mWkXo7zhncQQcOD62NA99O3Xh8PQ6urt@fTs4u6DNF3X618VpvDFlU7IUNhl@dHd3t9sf9bSPes8nV89TYvvcNVlIwRrbx7Q60EdjcaX0jGibujM3CNpHgp2PVafd@/TdK0nBWrtqp1mkf/wc): `^(xx?)*$`
1 later  -  [**10 bytes** - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrbuJGFP7PU5x42zADZguJuoowDsoSpETaTVYsUbebpZZjj2G0ZmzZ4w1Jlb99gD5iH6TpmQvgBKRaiZk5l@/cj6M878yj6PlNzBIuGHwaTcZHwej6fBzcXF1Og98uz6cXcNJ4w0WUVjGDQR4V7Ojt4rQRLcICgvx2Bj5MnPf399/vjqvfHx6@TBfv7hfk@Y/VkKxWQ9r66Zm@5joutHI/yNs9rwZdyoKLucLe0niGVBYuT3fkThtcSMjxKANWFFlBokyUErRfrSUry3DOKPxZyrjfj1ACBgOwZHXUdCbi1IOCyaoQ0POedjDVPcpi5sJdlqWQ@UmYlgpWm7Fwt0e/vpt5DcCHJ0B0ioI5sxiBlSIGh5gc34wuziYnLWqZLpT8kWUJ2Tj@y5pSk6eUaivqIRkMTRBRVknowyZQqsJztBpoD/rgvApeKzsOajnfhEM3@UjSqlyYSDZJaTw1KlHyuWAxpJmYm1coyntWeDphy4cgCtMU3bCx21twl2bRd2hFLvzIeAytOJQh5k4lSR3B94EoTosebjGoxW63N5Xp2sosQy4IAmgH81tshJQJktNOb@Z3PROC6Q7II98hw77j4ant5@bHoWQ4wv8DivQKEY@PAolFRV0FP8eDhq4DcZFXUqnrwLCE0CrY@r4MZbQIdCyt7dmgFaysUumaEnh2tD5ffh1rSpKUDJkYL4Ywl4sXAq3sB4skatlK4Iit7S9znjJim@Lzp@mE5tHbKEBnCXUtxtfx5DqYjicfL6/OpuPzNXn8ZTq@Olf3Q@2T/bWedOm2gw8KbECb@/o06LeVq4Xu72QjwHsoWZAU2TLIQylZIUiBXX518@GDBajr4OhKtpKYxPXJ38e3sGQHBSPYtOAawq31pbuvz14DGFMpX/I6SKdHvZpQzHL5v0IFi6qi5JnYK6jNJlkBers8bjoXN0aKS5iYQebCNb1HvXXH6/KgiuhiekKZcaIF1uXH@oueC3lWIttwcKnHpNlpWqPqET2VW5Q58Ot93u8LRRzuwYW2lm9Dj@LCEN0tltm1ypxg9@Z2K3rt3szDZbPETJDSheaqqRzDBJXInPk1/U0SuC/UDA580fOg3eb1iNdN@UgBnVJGSPObwJAwdSit@zMhzs8x/PPX34CfFo4ss0LQsZo1M0tqKF92l27M@kSh0xwHQv9texrPtozU23HO4A66cHhobRz4duomk@tJcHX98Ww6uqAvFHX71cZrvTFkUbFXNhh@dXZ0t9sf97eNeM8mV89TY/veN1hJwRjZxrc70EZgc6f1jWiYuDM2C9tEgp@O527n6PjfKEnDefncSbVO5@Q/): `^x?(xx?)*$`
2 later  -  [**16 bytes** - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXbbttGEH3XV4yZ1t6VqFRS0MAQTQuOLMAGEjlQZDSN4xA0uZQWoZYEuYxlt37tB/QT@yFVZy@SaEtACZvay8yZ25lhlOftWRStXsUs4YLBx@Fk1AuGV@ej4Hp8OQ1@uzyfXsBx4xUXUVrFDE7yqGC91/PTRjQPCwjym1vwYeK8u7//fvem@v3h4fN0/vZ@TlbfloPlgCyXA9ok3/6kP63oSxnHhWbuB3mr69UMlLLgYqYsbM94hqcsXJzuyJ02uJCQ41IGrCiygkSZKCVo75oLVpbhjFH4o5Rxvx@hBJycgD1WS33ORJx6UDBZFQK63tMOptpHWcxcuMuyFDI/CdNSwWozFu6m9@vbW68B@PAEiE5UMGMWI7BSxOAQk@nr4cXZ5LhJ7aULJX9kWUI2jv@yPqnJU0q1FfWQDAYmiCirJPRhEyhV4TlaDbQHfXBeBK@VHQe1nK/CoZt8JGlVzk0km6Q0nhqVKPlMsBjSTMzMKxTlPSs8nbDFQxCFaYpu2NjtLrhLs@g7NCMXfmQ8hmYcyhBzp5KkluD7QNRNkx5uMajFbrU2lenYyixCLggCaAfzGyRCygTJabt763c8E4JhB@SR75BB3/Fw1fJz8@NQMhji/wHF8woR3/QCiUVFXQU/w4WGrgNxkVdSqevAsITQLNh6vwhlNA90LM3t2qAVrKxS6ZoSeLbBPl1@GemTJCkZXmK8GMJMzp8JNLMfLJKoZSuBjba2v8h5yoglxaeP0wnNo9dRgM4S6lqML6PJVTAdTT5cjs@mo/P18ejzdDQ@V/tD7ZP9tZ506JbBBwUS0Oa@3g36beVqofs72QhwH0oWJEW2CPJQSlYIUiDLx9fv31uAug62rmRLiUlcr/x99xaW7KBgBBsKriHcGi/dfTx7CWBMpXzB6yDtLvVqQjHL5f8KFSyqipJnYq@gNptkBejp8rhhLk6MFEcxMY3MhWu4R70143V5UEV0MD2hzDjRAuvyY/1F14U8K/Ha3OBoj8lR@8gaVY/oqtyizIFf53m/L9ThYA8utLR8C7oUB4bobLHMrFXmBLs3uxvRbXVvPRw2C8wEKV04Wh4pxzBBJV7e@jX9TRK4L1QPnvii60GrxesRr0n5SAGdUkbI0VeBIWHqUFrzMyHOzzH889ffgJ8WjldmhKBjNWuml1RTPmeXJma9o9Bpjg2h/7acxrUtI/V2nDO4Jx04PLQ2DnzbdZPJ1SQYX304mw4v6DNFTb9ae60nhiwq9sIGw6/Oju52@uP8thHvmeTqeWps3/saKykYI9v4dhvaCGz2tD4RzSXOjM3ANpHgp2PVafd6/0ZJGs7KVTvVOu3j/wA): `^x?x?(xx?)*(^|)$`
3 later  -  [**22 bytes** - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXbbttGEH3XV4yZ1t6VqFRU0MAQTQuuLMAGEjlQZDSN4xA0uZQWoZYEuYwvjV/7Af3Efkjd2Ysk2hJQ2pL2MnPmdmYYF0V3HsdPrxKWcsHgw2g67oeji9NxeDk5n4W/n5/OzuCw9YqLOKsTBkdFXLL@68VxK15EJYTF1TUEMHV@u739dvOm/uP@/tNs8fZ2QZ6@3g3VH7m7G9I2@foD9z/oT0/0paTjQrsIwqLj@Q0zlSy5mCs7mzOe4ymLlsdbcsctLiQUuJQhK8u8JHEuKgnax/aSVVU0ZxT@rGQyGMQoAUdHYI/VUp8zkWQ@lEzWpQDPf9zCVPs4T5gLN3meQR6kUVYpWG3Gwl31f3177bcAH54C0ekK58xihFaKGBxi8n05OjuZHrapvXSh4g8sT8na8V9WJw15Sqm2oh6Sw9AEEee1hAGsA6UqPEergfZgAM6L4LWy46CW80U4dJ2PNKurhYlknZTWY6sWFZ8LlkCWi7n5ikR1y0pfJ2x5H8ZRlqEbNna7C2@yPP4G7diF7zlPoJ1EMsLcqSSpJQQBEHXTpvsbDGqxO511ZXq2MsuIC4IA2sHiComQMUEK2vWug55vQjDsgCIOHDIcOD6uOkFhfhxKhiP87FE8rxHxTT@UWFTUVfBzXGjoJhAXRS2Vug4MSwjtkq32y0jGi1DH0t6sDVrJqjqTrimBb9vs4/nnsT5J04rhJcaLIczl4plAO//OYolathLYbiv7y4JnjFhSfPwwm9Iifh2H6CyhrsX4PJ5ehLPx9P355GQ2Pl0djz/NxpNTtd/XPtlf60mPbhi8VyIBbe6b3aC/rVwj9GArGyHuI8nCtMyXYRFJyUpBSmT55PLdOwvQ1MHWlexOYhJXq2DXvYUlWygYwZqCKwi3wUt3F89eAhhTGV/yJkjXo35DKGGF/F@hksV1WfFc7BTUZtO8BD1dHtbMxYmR4UAmppG5cA33qL9ivC4PqogepieSOSdaYFV@rL/wXCjyCq/NDQ74hBx0D6xR9QhP5RZl9oImzwcDoQ6HO3Cho@U74FEcGKK3wTKzVpkT7NbsroTX8a59HDZLzASpXDi4O1COYYIqvLwOGvrrJPBAqB48CoTnQ6fDmxGvSPlAAZ1SRsjBF4EhYepQWvMzJc7PCfzz19@ArxaOV2aEoGMNa6aXVFM@Z5cmZrOj0GmODaH/N5zGtS0j9becM7hHPdjftzb2Att10@nFNJxcvD@Zjc7oM0VNv0Z7rSaGLGv2wgbDt86W7mb64/y2Ee@Y5Op5bG2@dzVWWjJGNvFtN7QRWO9pcyKaS5wZ64FtIsFXx1Ov2/f@jdMsmldP3UzrdA//Aw): `^x?x?x?(xx?)*(^|^x?|)$`
4 later  -  [**55 bytes** - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVX9TttIEP8/TzG4HOw6TpvQuwrFuBGFSCC1UKVB1ytwlrHXyarO2rLXJVD49x7gHvEe5LjZjySGRDoLnNnZmd98j@Oi6Ezi@OlVwlIuGHw@Gg33wqPz42F4cXY6Dn8/PR6fwH7rFRdxVicMDoq4ZHuvp@9b8TQqISwuryGAkfPh9vb7zdv6j7u7r@Ppu9spefqTDMggmM/nlMwH9Oevj2SOv@4DeSBzQgd0MN9G6uoDEgPysK05Lt1@oi@hHA/cIgiLds9v@FHJkouJcmTF4zlyWTR7vyb3vsWFhAJJGbKyzEsS56KSoINwZ6yqogmj8LOSSb8fowQcHIBlK1LzmUgyH0om61JAz39cw1TnOE@YBzd5nkEepFFWKVhtxsJd7v327tpvAT48BaLzGU6YxQitFDE4xBTk4ujkcLTvUnvpQcXvWZ6SpeNvFpyGPKVUW1EPyWFggojzWkIfloFSFZ6j1UB70AfnRfBa2XFQy7kSDl3mI83qamoiWSal9diqRcUngiWQ5WJiXpGoblnp64TN7sI4yjJ0w8ZuT@FNlsffwY09@JHzBNwkkhHmTiVJkRAEQNSNS3dWGNRit9vLynRtZWYRFwQBtIPFJTZCxgQpaKd3HXR9E4LpDijiwCGDvuMj1Q4K8@NQMjjC/y2K/BoR3@6FEouKugp@goSGbgJxUdRSqevAsITglmxxnkUynoY6FndFG7SSVXUmPVMC387hl9NvQ81J04rhJcaLIUzk9JmAm/9gsUQtWwmcx4X9WcEzRmxTfPk8HtEifh2H6CyhnsX4Nhydh@Ph6NPp2eF4eLxgD7@Oh2fH6ryjfbK/1pMuXXXwVokNaHPfnAb9tnKN0IO1bIR4jiQL0zKfhUUkJSsFKbHLzy4@frQATR0cXcnmEpO4oIJN9xaWrKFgBMsWXEB4jb70NvXZSwBjKuMz3gTp9KjfEEpYIf9XqGRxXVY8FxsFtdk0L0Fvl/tl5@LGyHBjEzPIXHim96i/6HhdHlQRXUxPJHNOtMCi/Fh/0fOgyCu8Njf4BUjIbmfXGlWP6KncosxW0Ozzfl8o5mADLrS1fBt6FBeG6K6wzK5V5gS7NadL0Wv3rn1cNjPMBKk82J3vKscwQRVeXgcN/WUSeCDUDB4EoudDu82bES@a8p4COqWMkN0rgSFh6lBa92dKnF8S@OevvwE/LRyvzApBxxrWzCypoXzeXboxmxOFTnMcCP236mmkbRmpv@acwT3ows6OtbEV2Kkbjc5H4dn5p8Px0Ql9pqjbrzFei40hy5q9sMHwq7Omu9r@uL9txBs2uXoeW6v3psFKS8bIKr71gTYCyzNtbkRziTtjubBNJPjpeOp29rr/xmkWTaqnTqZ1Ovv/AQ): `^(?(?=xxx)(x?){4}(xx?)*|(|(x()?)?x$|(x\B)?x?(|$)?)?x*)$`

To go 3 earlier or beyond, the rules would need to be extended to allow returning a negative sign via a capture group being set or unset (because there can't be a negative number of choices).

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
b=.5
f(n)=round((b+b5^b)^n/5^b)
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cigime5dwm)

f(n) = 1,1,2,3,5,... for n=1,2,3,4,5,...

Comment: [29 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5wts1l4w3j) using a regression.

Answer (score 1):

### [RASEL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/RASEL), 12 bytes.

```
1:.:3\01\--#
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 55 bytes

```go
func f(n int)int{if n<2{return n}
return f(n-1)+f(n-2)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BzoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMPK7M3IL8ohI9pbTcEqWlpSVpuhY3zdNK85IV0jTyFDLzSjSBuDozTSHPxqi6KLWktChPIa-WC8oCqtE11NQGUUaatVDtJmDtIMM1NKu50vKLFPKsbA2s82wMgYS2djVXQBHQzJw8jTwdkAGamly1XFC9CxZAaAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 4.5 bytes (9 nibbles)

```
.~~1+<2
```

```
.~~         # append until null (here this means forever)
   1        # starting with 1
    +       #   sum of
     <2     #   take 2 elements (or 1 if there's only 1)
```

[image]

---

[Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html) also supports a recursive approach to calculate the `n`-th element:
 ``` ``; $ -$2 1 + @-$2 @-$~ ``` (10 bytes = 20 nibbles)

```
``;                      # define a recursive function:
    $                    # initial input is arg1;
      -$2                # when input minus 2 is zero or negative:
          1              # return 1;
                         # otherwise:
            +            # add together
              @-$2       # recursive call with input minus 2
                   @-$~  # and recursive call with input minus 1
```

...although simply indexing into the infinite sequence is shorter: `=$.~~1+<2` (5 bytes = 10 nibbles).

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, <s>52</s> 50 bytes

```
=INDEX(ROUND((.5+SQRT(5)/2)^ROW(A:A)/SQRT(5),),A1)
```

<sup>Note: Excel will automatically add a leading zero to `.5` after you input the formula.</sup>

If you put a value in `A1`, you get that term (1-indexed) from the sequence. If you leave it blank, you get the first 1,474 terms which is when it gets too large for Excel to handle. As you can see below, it also loses accuracy at some point because Excel only keeps the first 15 digits of a number.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `Y`, \$7 \log_{256}(96) \approx\$ 6 bytes

(actually **5.76 bytes** but that doesn't show up on the leaderboard)

```
{xyAx+Y
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLqysqHSu0IyE8qODSaKVIpdhFhgYQLgA)

Returns the 0-indexed \$n\$<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number.

**Explanation:**

```python
{xyAx+Y   # Implicit input
{         # Loop that many times:
 xy  +    #  Add x and y together
  yAx     #  While storing y in x
      Y   #  And storing the result in y
          # After the loop, the Y flag pushes y
          # Which is output implicitly afterwards
```

Note that `x` defaults to 0 and `y` defaults to 1.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 11 bytes

```
yy$K1<.<scp
```

Uses a new version that doesn't work on ATO yet :(

### Explanation

The basic idea is to use the fact that each element of the sequence is one more than the sum of all elements 2 or more steps before it.

For example, by the time we have

```
1,1,2,3,5,8
```

To get the next element we sum everything but the last element (`8`)

```
1+1+2+3+5 = 12
```

and add 1

```
1,1,2,3,5,8,13
```

If we set up the first two elements we can use this property to generate the entire sequence.

---

`yy` is the fixed point combinator, it can be very hard to understand if you aren't used to wacky recursive schemes, so we will just rewrite things without it:

```
f=K1<.<scp$f
```

`<.<` is a fancy compose which composes its first argument on both sides of the second, so once again we can rewrite this longer as:

```
f=K1<scp<K1$f
```

`K1` is a shortcut for `(1:)` which adds `1` to the front of a list.

```
f=1:(scp$1:f)
```

`scp` gives the cumulative sums of a list. This is the part that establishes the property which builds the next element.

## 11 bytes

```haskell
f=1:lS(+)1f
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNxczcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRMDS0pI0XYvVabaGVjnBGtqahmkQkZtKuYmZeQq2Cin5XAoKBUUKKjCteiWJ2akKhgYKUJULFkBoAA)

### Explanation

This pretty straight-fowardly ports the [Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89/56656). Same score as the other one but less interesting.

### Reflections

There are some nice things here, I feel the first answer works well and I'm happy with the functions it is using. But I can still see somethings that could probably be improved.

- There should be builtins for dealing with Fibonacci numbers eventually.  They are a common subject of code-golf challenges
- `lS mp` is probably useful. `scp` and `scs` are very similar, however they are required to not alter the length of the structure involved, while `lS mp` always makes the structure one longer.  This is essential for the second answer to work, so we can't use `scs` as a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ÆF
```

Given `n`, outputs the `n`th Fibonacci number (1-indexed).

Built-in solution. In Thunno 2.1.5, a non-built-in alternative will be **4 bytes**:

```
1µµ+
```

Starting from `1`, generates an infinite sequence (`µµ`), where the next term is found by adding (`+`) the previous two terms together.

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: *Almost* a polyglot with Jelly…

Comment: So close... But I'm not surprised: Thunno 2 and Jelly both use the same starting character for "math digraphs"

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bttxzh7npy), 11 bytes

`a->a+b,b->a`

Add sliders, then click arrow repeatedly

Comment: `\to ` can be shortened to `->`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 6 bytes

`1#Måâ+`

takes n as input, computes the n-th Fibonacci number (0-indexed)

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=MSNN5eIr&in=MTA=)

### Explanation

```
1      ; push 1
 #M    ; for every number in the 1-based range to the input
   å   ; ignore that number
    â  ; push the top value below the 2nd value
     + ; add the top two values
       ; implicit output
```

---

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md) , 10 bytes

Directly computes the n-th Fibonacci number using Matrix powers, sadly a bit longer than the other solution

`1ä,1)#^M¡M`

takes n as input, computes the n-th Fibonacci number (1-indexed)

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=MeQsMSkjXk2hTQ==&in=MTA=)

### Explanation

```
(1ä,1)        ; the matrix [[1,1],[1,0]] (the opening bracket at the start can be left out)
       ^      ; to the power of
      #       ; the input
        M¡M   ; get the lower left element
        M¡    ; push the rows of the matrix reversed
          M   ; push all elements of the reversed lower row
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3.8, 36 bytes

I did not come up with this solution, so I'm making it Community wiki. However, it's beautiful, and you should read the [blog post](https://orlp.net/blog/magical-fibonacci-formulae/) about it, from which I got the program.

```python
lambda n:(b:=2<<n)**n*b//(b*b-b-1)%b
```

[**Attempt This Online**](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3VXISc5NSEhXyrDSSrGyNbGzyNLW08rSS9PU1krSSdJN0DTVVk6BqVfNsDQ24Cooy80o0otM0KjQV0vKLFCoUMvMUihLz0lM18jRjNa0hihcsgNAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)’s type system, 97 bytes

```typescript
//@ts-ignore
type F<N,L=[],A=[1],B=A>=L extends{length:N}?A["length"]:F<N,[...L,1],B,[...A,...B]>
```

[Try it at the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTACBcGcFoEsHMB2B7ATgUwLAChwE8AHdAAgDEAeAOQBoAZAXgG0BdagQSYEZWAhetgHz1axdAA9w6RABNIAbwA2U+OAAWALkoBfAPxtGAIiWIVqg83UUajAHR3a1btR7VbdttTs2ezAThz4RMQAZgAMxPRk5KF+2CDECQB6OgGEJMGcEVGcsfFJKbhpIQBMWRTFucAJxMmpQcEAzGXkDZXVtYX1ACzNXW35dekArM1D-TUFgekAbM3T4x1TIQDszcsLk0XBABzN2xuDIQCczUcHnemc4ZEUV+dLGZk35Jw5OHkThxmlz5wV71UBhcQpwmr9WgD2pt6pwer8+pCgQ9OCNfmNEZ9gRlZr95hjFltOKtfut8dDLrtfvsyV9OCdfmcaVjitcoiy2lcjl1ZgJiABbACGYmIsEQ4BFkGIR2lR0hanQaHQ4FgAGMBQoFHhiCrkABXBTSYjwZDEZCIYi6sWwBRRGW8gBGuvFguF4F1BCUEuI4GQJsggo1OCAA)

This is a generic type `F` taking a number type `N` and outputting the Nth Fibonacci number, 0-indexed.

This solution won’t work past the first 20 Fibonacci numbers because of the max int (technically, max tuple size) limit.

Explanation: We start with the input number `N`, and `L=[],A=[1],B=A`. L keeps track of which Fibonacci number we’re on, and A and B are unary numbers (tuple-types of 1s) that track \$ f(n) \$ and \$ f(n + 1) \$ respectively.

First, check if `L extends{length:N}` (the length of L is N). If it is (`?`), return `A["length"]` (A as a decimal number).

Otherwise (`:`), recurse (`F<…>`), keeping N the same, increasing L’s length by 1 (`[...L,1]`), setting A to B, and setting B to A + B (`[...A,...B]`).

Alternatively, this can be done in 77 bytes with I/O in unary:

```
//@ts-ignore
type F<N,A=[1],B=A>=N extends[1,...infer N]?F<N,B,[...A,...B]>:A
```

[Try it at the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTACBcGcFoEsHMB2B7ATgUwLAChwE8AHdAAgDEAeAOQBoBBAXgG0BGAXWoCF7aA+ey4ugAe4dIgAmkFtQB0c2IgBm6VMUqsA-BRodqjOTNqy5HVjwBctHDnxFiigAzF6ZcozM4QxbwD0NNwhJFZmdXFg9sL19-XED7ACZQimk2Hk9gb2I-ALtFAGYkt2ZqYtT0zOzY3IAWQpSSkoiorJjbIIBWOtKG0qaM6JyggDYunrGyyP6WwfsAdlHuxca0yYrWuMUADgXx8b61mcUATh2ls-2BqqDmJxdks93Fi+mr+2YQu6LH796V5sq2m9Ep96g8wctypdAcECiDwfCes8ARtmLU4T8MU8-lNkblmJ10QiiRDVlCUSNCZiqb9IS9ocx5pTicykes8dsmdSuRN-mzridOczuazytD4rcwkKpXtscQbkdqiMeMQALYAQyExAU4C1kGIRwNR1FAAt0Gh0OBYABjNUAG1teGIVuQAFdbeJiPBkMRkIhiC7EJbba5DcqAEYunXqzXgF0EW0kWB68DIb2QdX2nBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 13 bytes

```
1
:!\
{ :
=+}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fkMtKMYarWsGKy1a79v//f/kFJZn5ecX/dVMA)

Infinitely prints fibonacci numbers separated by newlines.

```
1    Set up the stack to [(implicit 0) 1]

     Loop with stack content [x y]:
:!\  :!\   print y and a newline
{ :  :}    [x y | y]
=+}  +     [x+y | y]
     =     [y | x+y]
     {     [y x+y]
```

Answer (score 0):

## C / Objective-c, 62

```
c;f(a,b){printf("%d ",a+b);if(c++<40)f(a+b,a);}main(){f(0,1);}
```

This will print the first 40 fibonacci numbers. I assume the compiler will set c=0. If it is trash, than it will not work;

This version is smaller, but it infite show all sequence number

## C / Objective-c, 50 (infinite)

```
f(a,b){printf("%d ",a+b);f(a+b,a);}main(){f(0,1);}
```

Comment: Variables with static duration are zero-initialized if not explicitly initialized. This behavior is required by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP, Finite - 46 chars**

```
<?for($b=1;$i++<$n;)echo$b-$a=($b+=$a)-$a,"
";
```

where $n is the length of the sequence

**PHP, Infinite - 39 chars**

```
<?for($b=1;;)echo$b-$a=($b+=$a)-$a,"
";
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB/Octave, n first numbers, <strike>41</strike> 39 chars

```
a=0:1;for(i=3:n);a(i)=a(i-2)+a(i-1);end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3 (53)

```
def f(n):
 l,p=0,1
 while n:n,l,p=n-1,p,l+p
 return l
```

Comment: [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI08nx9ZAp8DWUNMqtSI1WSkHyC7QydEusFbSyrMuKMrMK1HI@Z@bWKCRplOUmJeeqmFpqan5HwA).

Answer (score 0):

**Clojure, 46**

```
(defn f[x y z](if(= 0 z)x(recur y(+ y x)(- z 1))))
```

Although, technically 50 since Clojure requires the recur for pseudo tail call:

```
(defn f[x y z](if(= 0 z)x(recur y(+ y x)(- z 1))))
```

Non compressed:

```
(defn fib [left right iteration]   
  (if (= 0  iteration)
    left
    (fib right (+ right left)  (- iteration 1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell: 27 (21) characters

It almost feels like cheating to use Haskell for something like this. It just prints Fibonacci numbers ad infinitum.

```
f=1:scanl(+)1f
main=print f
```

And if using GHCi only 21 characters, including two newlines, are necessary:

```
Prelude>let f=1:scanl(+)1f
Prelude>f
[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21...
```

Comment: this solution [was already posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89/5021) here. FYI.

Answer (score 0):

**JAVA - 108 characters:**

```
int[]f={0,1};System.out.println(0);for(int i=0;i<9;i+=2)System.out.printf("%d\n%d\n",f[0]+=f[1],f[1]+=f[0]);
```

Comment: If a space is required in the code, it should be included in the character count.

Comment: Alright, I will update it.

Comment: Already fixed it for you - looks like someone approved my edit suggestion.

Comment: That was me - I went to fix it, and found you had already.

Comment: Ah. All good, then. Welcome to [codegolf.se]!

Answer (score 0):

## C 64 Characters

```
a;main(f,n){scanf("%d",&n);while(--n)f+=a=f-a;printf("%d",f-a);}
```

This will print the nth Fibonacci number.

A more readable format :

```
a;
main(f,n){
scanf("%d",&n);
while(--n)
   f+=a=f-a;
printf("%d",f-a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6) - 24 Characters

```
f=x=>x<3?1:f(x-1)+f(x-2)
```

### JavaScript - 24 Characters (snippet)

```
for(a=b=1;--n;a=b-a)b+=a
```

Set a value for `n` and it will calculate the nth Fibonacci value.

Comment: Also, the second solution is invalid as it's a snippet and not a full program / function.

Answer (score 0):

**F#, 63 chars:**

```
let rec g x y n=if n=x then x else f (n-1) y (x+y)
let f=g 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## ~-~! (No Comment) - 27

```
'=|*>~[<'&*-~>+<'&*-~~>]*|:
```

Didn't think it'd be this short.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby - 49 characters

Nobody has done a Ruby solution for the second problem so I thought I'd give that a go:

```
p Hash.new{|h,k|k<2?k:(h[k-2]+h[k-1])}[gets.to_i]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 53 bytes

```
a=[1,1];setInterval('a.push(a[b=a.length-1]+a[b-1])')
```

I decided to use a new approach to create an infinite stream. Works anywhere else but Firefox.

To get the array of integers, simply do `a` from the console.

Answer (score 0):

## CoffeeScript, 63 bytes

```
j=0;k=1;a=[];a=((i=j+k;k=j;j=i) for i in [0..prompt()]);alert a
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 45 bytes

Simple, iterative approach. Exits when signed integer overflows.

```c
a;main(b){for(;b>0;printf("%d ",a=b-a))b+=a;}
```

Try it [here](http://ideone.com/D8G3Z5).

Comment: I seems to me you can remove `b>0` condition.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pylons](https://github.com/morganthrapp/Pylons-lang), 13 bytes

Takes the number of iterations as a command line argument to the interpreter.

```
11fA..+@{A,i}
```

How it works:

```
11  # Pushes 1, 1 to the stack.
fA#.##.#+@  # Creates a function "A" that takes the top two elements of the stack and adds them.
{A,i}  # Calls A sys.argv[1] times.
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Ouroboros](http://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/Ouroboros), 10 bytes

Outputs an infinite Fibonacci sequence, starting at 0, separated by newlines.

```
.!+.@.nao+
```

#### Explanation

Each line of an Ouroboros program represents a [snake eating its own tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros). When execution reaches the end of the line, it loops back to the beginning. Each snake has a stack to store values.

If this is the first pass through the code, we need to initialize the stack by turning the top into a `1`. (The empty stack is treated as containing infinite zeros.) `.!` dups and logically negates (`1` if the value was `0`, otherwise `0`), and `+` adds that result to the top value. This has the effect of pushing a `1` if the stack was empty, and doing nothing if the stack contained a nonzero value.

Now, call the two numbers on the stack `x` and `y`, where `x` is smaller and `y` is on the top of the stack. `.@.n` copies `y`, rotates `x` to the top, and outputs a copy of it. `a` pushes `10` and `o` outputs it as a character (printing a newline). Finally, `+` adds `x` to a copy of `y`. The stack now contains `y` and `x+y`, and we proceed to the next iteration.

#### Try it out

```js
// Define Stack class
function Stack() {
  this.stack = [];
  this.length = 0;
}
Stack.prototype.push = function(item) {
  this.stack.push(item);
  this.length++;
}
Stack.prototype.pop = function() {
  var result = 0;
  if (this.length > 0) {
    result = this.stack.pop();
    this.length--;
  }
  return result;
}
Stack.prototype.top = function() {
  var result = 0;
  if (this.length > 0) {
    result = this.stack[this.length - 1];
  }
  return result;
}
Stack.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "" + this.stack;
}

// Define Snake class
function Snake(code) {
  this.code = code;
  this.length = this.code.length;
  this.ip = 0;
  this.ownStack = new Stack();
  this.currStack = this.ownStack;
  this.alive = true;
  this.wait = 0;
  this.partialString = this.partialNumber = null;
}
Snake.prototype.step = function() {
  if (!this.alive) {
    return null;
  }
  if (this.wait > 0) {
    this.wait--;
    return null;
  }
  var instruction = this.code.charAt(this.ip);
  var output = null;
  console.log("Executing instruction " + instruction);
  if (this.partialString !== null) {
    // We're in the middle of a double-quoted string
    if (instruction == '"') {
      // Close the string and push its character codes in reverse order
      for (var i = this.partialString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.currStack.push(this.partialString.charCodeAt(i));
      }
      this.partialString = null;
    } else {
      this.partialString += instruction;
    }
  } else if (instruction == '"') {
    this.partialString = "";
  } else if ("0" <= instruction && instruction <= "9") {
    if (this.partialNumber !== null) {
      this.partialNumber = this.partialNumber + instruction;  // NB: concatenation!
    } else {
      this.partialNumber = instruction;
    }
    next = this.code.charAt((this.ip + 1) % this.length);
    if (next < "0" || "9" < next) {
      // Next instruction is non-numeric, so end number and push it
      this.currStack.push(+this.partialNumber);
      this.partialNumber = null;
    }
  } else if ("a" <= instruction && instruction <= "f") {
    // a-f push numbers 10 through 15
    var value = instruction.charCodeAt(0) - 87;
    this.currStack.push(value);
  } else if (instruction == "$") {
    // Toggle the current stack
    if (this.currStack === this.ownStack) {
      this.currStack = this.program.sharedStack;
    } else {
      this.currStack = this.ownStack;
    }
  } else if (instruction == "s") {
    this.currStack = this.ownStack;
  } else if (instruction == "S") {
    this.currStack = this.program.sharedStack;
  } else if (instruction == "l") {
    this.currStack.push(this.ownStack.length);
  } else if (instruction == "L") {
    this.currStack.push(this.program.sharedStack.length);
  } else if (instruction == ".") {
    var item = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(item);
    this.currStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "m") {
    var item = this.ownStack.pop();
    this.program.sharedStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "M") {
    var item = this.program.sharedStack.pop();
    this.ownStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "y") {
    var item = this.ownStack.top();
    this.program.sharedStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "Y") {
    var item = this.program.sharedStack.top();
    this.ownStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "\\") {
    var top = this.currStack.pop();
    var next = this.currStack.pop()
    this.currStack.push(top);
    this.currStack.push(next);
  } else if (instruction == "@") {
    var c = this.currStack.pop();
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(b);
    this.currStack.push(c);
    this.currStack.push(a);
  } else if (instruction == ";") {
    this.currStack.pop();
  } else if (instruction == "+") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a + b);
  } else if (instruction == "-") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a - b);
  } else if (instruction == "*") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a * b);
  } else if (instruction == "/") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a / b);
  } else if (instruction == "%") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a % b);
  } else if (instruction == "_") {
    this.currStack.push(-this.currStack.pop());
  } else if (instruction == "I") {
    var value = this.currStack.pop();
    if (value < 0) {
      this.currStack.push(Math.ceil(value));
    } else {
      this.currStack.push(Math.floor(value));
    }
  } else if (instruction == ">") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(+(a > b));
  } else if (instruction == "<") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(+(a < b));
  } else if (instruction == "=") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(+(a == b));
  } else if (instruction == "!") {
    this.currStack.push(+ !this.currStack.pop());
  } else if (instruction == "?") {
    this.currStack.push(Math.random());
  } else if (instruction == "n") {
    output = "" + this.currStack.pop();
  } else if (instruction == "o") {
    output = String.fromCharCode(this.currStack.pop());
  } else if (instruction == "r") {
    var input = this.program.io.getNumber();
    this.currStack.push(input);
  } else if (instruction == "i") {
    var input = this.program.io.getChar();
    this.currStack.push(input);
  } else if (instruction == "(") {
    this.length -= Math.floor(this.currStack.pop());
    this.length = Math.max(this.length, 0);
  } else if (instruction == ")") {
    this.length += Math.floor(this.currStack.pop());
    this.length = Math.min(this.length, this.code.length);
  } else if (instruction == "w") {
    this.wait = this.currStack.pop();
  }
  // Any unrecognized character is a no-op
  if (this.ip >= this.length) {
    // We've swallowed the IP, so this snake dies
    this.alive = false;
    this.program.snakesLiving--;
  } else {
    // Increment IP and loop if appropriate
    this.ip = (this.ip + 1) % this.length;
  }
  return output;
}
Snake.prototype.getHighlightedCode = function() {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < this.code.length; i++) {
    if (i == this.length) {
      result += '<span class="swallowedCode">';
    }
    if (i == this.ip) {
      if (this.wait > 0) {
        result += '<span class="nextActiveToken">';
      } else {
        result += '<span class="activeToken">';
      }
      result += escapeEntities(this.code.charAt(i)) + '</span>';
    } else {
      result += escapeEntities(this.code.charAt(i));
    }
  }
  if (this.length < this.code.length) {
    result += '</span>';
  }
  return result;
}

// Define Program class
function Program(source, speed, io) {
  this.sharedStack = new Stack();
  this.snakes = source.split(/\r?\n/).map(function(snakeCode) {
    var snake = new Snake(snakeCode);
    snake.program = this;
    snake.sharedStack = this.sharedStack;
    return snake;
  }.bind(this));
  this.snakesLiving = this.snakes.length;
  this.io = io;
  this.speed = speed || 10;
  this.halting = false;
}
Program.prototype.run = function() {
  this.step();
  if (this.snakesLiving) {
    this.timeout = window.setTimeout(this.run.bind(this), 1000 / this.speed);
  }
}
Program.prototype.step = function() {
   for (var s = 0; s < this.snakes.length; s++) {
    var output = this.snakes[s].step();
    if (output) {
      this.io.print(output);
    }
  }
  this.io.displaySource(this.snakes.map(function (snake) {
      return snake.getHighlightedCode();
    }).join("<br>"));
 }
Program.prototype.halt = function() {
  window.clearTimeout(this.timeout);
}

var ioFunctions = {
  print: function (item) {
    var stdout = document.getElementById('stdout');
    stdout.value += "" + item;
  },
  getChar: function () {
    if (inputData) {
      var inputChar = inputData[0];
      inputData = inputData.slice(1);
      result = inputChar.charCodeAt(0);
    } else {
      result = -1;
    }
    var stdinDisplay = document.getElementById('stdin-display');
    stdinDisplay.innerHTML = escapeEntities(inputData);
    return result;
  },
  getNumber: function () {
    while (inputData && (inputData[0] < "0" || "9" < inputData[0])) {
      inputData = inputData.slice(1);
    }
    if (inputData) {
      var inputNumber = inputData.match(/\d+/)[0];
      inputData = inputData.slice(inputNumber.length);
      result = +inputNumber;
    } else {
      result = -1;
    }
    var stdinDisplay = document.getElementById('stdin-display');
    stdinDisplay.innerHTML = escapeEntities(inputData);
    return result;
  },
  displaySource: function (formattedCode) {
    var sourceDisplay = document.getElementById('source-display');
    sourceDisplay.innerHTML = formattedCode;
  }
};
var program = null;
var inputData = null;
function showEditor() {
  var source = document.getElementById('source'),
    sourceDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('source-display-wrapper'),
    stdin = document.getElementById('stdin'),
    stdinDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('stdin-display-wrapper');
  
  source.style.display = "block";
  stdin.style.display = "block";
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.display = "none";
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.display = "none";
  
  source.focus();
}
function hideEditor() {
  var source = document.getElementById('source'),
    sourceDisplay = document.getElementById('source-display'),
    sourceDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('source-display-wrapper'),
    stdin = document.getElementById('stdin'),
    stdinDisplay = document.getElementById('stdin-display'),
    stdinDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('stdin-display-wrapper');
  
  source.style.display = "none";
  stdin.style.display = "none";
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.display = "block";
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.display = "block";
  
  var sourceHeight = getComputedStyle(source).height,
    stdinHeight = getComputedStyle(stdin).height;
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.minHeight = sourceHeight;
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.maxHeight = sourceHeight;
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.minHeight = stdinHeight;
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.maxHeight = stdinHeight;
  sourceDisplay.textContent = source.value;
  stdinDisplay.textContent = stdin.value;
}
function escapeEntities(input) {
  return input.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
function resetProgram() {
  var stdout = document.getElementById('stdout');
  stdout.value = null;
  if (program !== null) {
    program.halt();
  }
  program = null;
  inputData = null;
  showEditor();
}
function initProgram() {
  var source = document.getElementById('source'),
    stepsPerSecond = document.getElementById('steps-per-second'),
    stdin = document.getElementById('stdin');
  program = new Program(source.value, +stepsPerSecond.innerHTML, ioFunctions);
  hideEditor();
  inputData = stdin.value;
}
function runBtnClick() {
  if (program === null || program.snakesLiving == 0) {
    resetProgram();
    initProgram();
  } else {
    program.halt();
    var stepsPerSecond = document.getElementById('steps-per-second');
    program.speed = +stepsPerSecond.innerHTML;
  }
  program.run();
}
function stepBtnClick() {
  if (program === null) {
    initProgram();
  } else {
    program.halt();
  }
  program.step();
}
function sourceDisplayClick() {
  resetProgram();
}
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.so-box {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .3em .7em;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.1;
    border: 1px solid #c47b07;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background: #f88912;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset;
}
.control {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 6px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.option {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    float: left;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
input, textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea {
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 25px;
}
span[contenteditable] {
    padding: 2px 6px;
    background: #cc7801;
    color: #fff;
}
#stdout-container, #stdin-container {
    height: auto;
    padding: 6px 0;
}
#reset {
    float: right;
}
#source-display-wrapper , #stdin-display-wrapper{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#source-display , #stdin-display{
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 2px;
}
.activeToken {
    background: #f93;
}
.nextActiveToken {
    background: #bbb;
}
.swallowedCode{
    color: #999;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content:".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--
Designed and written 2015 by D. Loscutoff
Much of the HTML and CSS was taken from this Befunge interpreter by Ingo Bürk: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40331/16766
-->
<div class="container">
<textarea id="source" placeholder="Enter your program here" wrap="off">.!+.@.nao+</textarea>
<div id="source-display-wrapper" onclick="sourceDisplayClick()"><div id="source-display"></div></div></div><div id="stdin-container" class="container">
<textarea id="stdin" placeholder="Input" wrap="off"></textarea>
<div id="stdin-display-wrapper" onclick="stdinDisplayClick()"><div id="stdin-display"></div></div></div><div id="controls-container" class="container clearfix"><input type="button" id="run" class="control so-box" value="Run" onclick="runBtnClick()" /><input type="button" id="pause" class="control so-box" value="Pause" onclick="program.halt()" /><input type="button" id="step" class="control so-box" value="Step" onclick="stepBtnClick()" /><input type="button" id="reset" class="control so-box" value="Reset" onclick="resetProgram()" /></div><div id="stdout-container" class="container"><textarea id="stdout" placeholder="Output" wrap="off" readonly></textarea></div><div id="options-container" class="container"><div class="option so-box">Steps per Second:
<span id="steps-per-second" contenteditable>20</span></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 33 bytes

Recursively calculates the nth fibbonacci number.

```
f(n){return n>1?f(n-1)+f(n-2):n;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, <s>32</s> 26 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder!

`±1=±2=1;±n_:=±(n-1)+±(n-2)`

Recursive function, returns nth value in sequence.

Comment: You can golf this with prefix notation: `f@1=f@2=1;f@n_:=f[n-1]+f[n-2]`. And even further by defining an operator instead: `±1=±2=1;±n_:=±(n-1)+±(n-2)`.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about prefix notation here. Didn't know about the operator, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6)

A couple of different ES6 implementations. The first two return the `n`th Fibonacci number and the third returns an array of the first `n` Fibonacci numbers. Non-competing, obviously.

### 30 bytes

```js
f=

(n,x=1,y=0)=>!n?y:f(n-1,x+y,x)

console.log(f(10))
```

### 46 bytes

```js
f=

n=>(x=1,y=0,eval("while(n--)[x,y]=[x+y,x]"),y)

console.log(f(10))
```

### 46 bytes

```js
f=

n=>(a=[],(f=x=>a[x]=x<2?x:f(--x)+f(--x))(n),a)

console.log(f(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 71 bytes (function implementation=43, Enter=1, call=27)

```
proc F x {expr $x>1?\[F $x-1]+\[F $x-2]:$x}
while 1 {puts [F [incr i]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFNoUKhOrWioEhBpcLO0D4m2g3I0DWM1YayjGKtVCpqucozMnNSFQwVqgtKS4oVgFLRmXnJRQqZsbG1//8DAA)

Serves both purposes: Has a function `F` that allows calculate the `x`'th Fibonacci number. then it is called to show on stdout `F` applied to the whole range of positive integers.

Comment: **tcl,89**: Different approach — iterative. [demo](http://rextester.com/NGVZF48005) — but it does not have a function and fails to represent the first one.

Comment: Failed outgolf; **tcl,91 (function implementation=56, Enter=1, call=34)**:  https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WaEkOcfKKjexJCOtNC/ZyspNoUKhOrWioEihWqXCztDeTUOlQtdQUxtMG2laqVTU1nKVZ2TmpCoYKlQXlJYUK0SDlbtpRGfmJRcpZMZqxtYq/P8PAA

Comment: You can use less `expr` as there's a leading one, in escaping evaluation of each 1st brackets [code 45B](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFNIU@hOrWioEhBJc/GyF4lzyomOg3I1jWKVdBWgLINY2v/F5SWFCsAuYaGsf8B)

Comment: Thanks @david . I did not know I could do it by escaping `[` with `\\`. I bet I have some more answers I can golf them the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

## [Implicit](//github.com/aaronryank/SimpleStack), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
]3.(,[+%:]ß
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/z/WWE9DJ1pb1Sr28Pz//wE)

**10 bytes** (knock off the `ß`) if we don't need delimiters. It's not specified in the challenge... [TIO](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/z/WWE9DJ1pb1Sr2/38A)

This is my own (rather simple) method of computing the sequence. Explanation:

```
#::.(,[+%:]ß
#::.            push 0, 0, 1 (push stack length, duplicate twice, increment last one)
    (.......    forever (implicit ¶ at end of program)
     ,           swap top two stack values
      [          pop stack into memory
       +         add top two stack values
        %        print
         :       duplicate top of stack
          ]      push memory to stack
           ß     print a space
```

In a normal language, say, C, it would look like this:

```
int x, y, z;
x = 0; y = 0; z = 1;

do {
    swap(&y, &z);
    x += y;
    y = x;
    printf("%d ",x);
} while (1);
```

Equivalence:

```
int x = 0, y = 0, z = 1;   // #::.
do {                       // (
    swap(&y,&z);           // ,
                           // [ (z is ignored below)
    x += y;                // +
    y = x;                 // :
    printf("%d ",x);       // %ß
                           // ] (z is ignored above)
} while (1);               // ¶
```

Here's how the stack looks after each operation that modifies it:

```
#  0
:  0 0
:  0 0 0
.  0 0 1

,  0 1 0
[  0 1
+  1
%  1
:  1 1
]  1 1 0

,  1 0 1
[  1 0
+  1
%  1
:  1 1
]  1 1 1

,  1 1 1
[  1 1
+  2
%  2
:  2 2
]  2 2 1

,  2 1 2
[  2 1
+  3
%  3
:  3 3
]  3 3 2

,  3 2 3
[  3 2
+  5
%  5
:  5 5
]  5 5 3

,  5 3 5
[  5 3
+  8
%  8
:  8 8
]  8 8 5

,  8 5 8
[  8 5
+  13
%  13
:  13 13
]  13 13 8

,  13 8 13
[  13 8
+  21
%  21
:  21 21
]  21 21 13

,  21 13 21
[  21 13
+  34
%  34
:  34 34
]  34 34 21
```

Golf notes:

- `]3.` is shorter than `#::.` which is shorter than `:0::1` which is shorter than `:0:0:1`.
- `ß` is shorter than `@32`.
- `(...` is shorter than `:1(;...:1)`.

(`ß`, `¶`, and implicit `¶` added during the writing of this program.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pug](https://pugjs.org/), 30 bytes

### Without input (infinite)

```
-a=b=1
while 1
 =a
 -b=a+(a=b)
```

Will produce an output:

```
1123581321345589144233377610...
```

---

#### With an output delimiter: 34 bytes

```
-a=b=1
while 1
 =a+" "
 -b=a+(a=b)
```

Will produce an output:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89...
```

---

#### With HTML as an output delimiter: 31 bytes

```
-a=b=1
while 1
 p=a
 -b=a+(a=b)
```

Although I doubt this is compliant to the challenge's rules, this will produce:

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>13</p>
<p>21</p>
<p>34</p>
<p>55</p>
...
```

---

### With input (as a funcion; finite)

#### Without an output delimiter, 47 bytes

```
mixin f(n)
 -a=b=1
 while n--
  =a
  -b=a+(a=b)
```

For an input `n=10`, for example, it produces:

```
11235813213455
```

Just as it is with the infinite series versions:

- +4 bytes (`+" "`) = **51 bytes** for a space delimiter
- +1 byte (`p`) = **48 bytes** for an HTML `<p>` tag delimiter

Answer (score 0):

## [Momema](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/momema), 28 bytes

```
1 1z0-8*01+*1*00+*1-*0-9 9z1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83PTc1N/P/fUMGwykDXQsvAUFvLUMvAAEjqahnoWipYVhn@/w8A) Outputs infinitely with a tab between numbers.

If no separator between numbers is required, you can save four bytes:

```
1 1z0-8*01+*1*00+*1-*0z1
```

### Explanation

```
                                                     #  a = 0
1   1       #            [1] = 1                     #  b = 1
z   0       #  label z0: jump past label z0 (no-op)  #  while true {
-8  *0      #            output num [0]              #    print a
1   +*1*0   #            [1] = [1] + [0]             #    b = a + b
0   +*1-*0  #            [0] = [1] - [0]             #    a = b - a
-9  9       #            output chr 9                #    print '\t'
z1          #  label z1: jump past label z0          #  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Reflections, 93 bytes

```
     \
/*\/#  (0:0\
* 0\_*;(0\/ :(0\
  \     v/#@/_ /
\  (1/ 1)0)*
        : \\/
        \(1/
```

[Test it!](https://thewastl.github.io/Reflections/reflections.html##ICAgICBcCi8qXC8jICAoMDowXAoqIDBcXyo7KDBcLyA6KDBcCiAgXCAgICAgdi8jQC9fIC8KXCAgKDEvIDEpMCkqCiAgICAgICAgOiBcXC8KICAgICAgICBcKDEv/zH/MP8w/w==)

#### Explanation:

**Initialisation**

Executing `\*/(1\*/*\0\`.

- `*` at (5|2) pushes 5×2=10 (\n)
- `(1` moves the newline to stack 1
- `*` at (0|2) pushes 0×2=0 (`F(-1)`)
- `*` at (1|1) pushes 1×1=1 (`F(0)`)
- `0` moves these two values to stack 0

**Loop**

Executing `v1):\(1/\\0)#/:(0\/_//\*@\0:(0#/\_*;(0\/`.

- `1)` pulls the newline from stack 1
- `:` duplicates it
- `(1` moves the duplicate to stack 1
- `0)` pulls the last result from stack 0
- `#` redefines (0|0)
- `:` duplicates the last result
- `(0` moves the duplicate back to stack 0
- `_` at (3|0) converts the last result to a list of digits
- `*` at (1|1) pushes 1×1=1
- `@` prints the last result and a newline
- `0` pulls both values from stack 0
- `:` duplicates the top one (newer one)
- `(0` pushes the duplicate back to stack 0
- `#` redefines (0|0)
- `_` at (0|1) adds the two values together
- `*` at (1|1) pushes 1×1=1
- `;` pops that again
- `(0` pushes the new result to stack 0

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

```
|5
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7C5&i=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5&a=1&m=2)

Added for completeness. An internal that returns 0-indexed Fibonacci number.

Infinite sequence generator without using the internal:

```
ò¶AÄ∟
```

The ASCII equivalent is

```
01WQb+
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 28 bytes

```
F.,1DEF F X,Y?Y
F Y,X+Y
END
```

### Ungolfed:

```
F 0,1
DEF F X,Y
 PRINT Y
 F Y,X+Y
END
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 49 bytes

Defines a function to get the `n`th fibonacci number. 1-indexed (starts at 0).

Simple recursive formula. Slow.

```
def f(n)when n<2,do: n
def f(n),do: f(n-1)+f(n-2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@p@Smpabn1Kak6rglpmUn5eYnJypkJIPElZI08jTLM9IzVPIszHSScm3UsjjggmDuUCGrqGmNogy0vyfmpfCxZWWX6SQp2Cjq2Cop2dsADSIi9PTXy8zr7ggNbkEYYMe2AyFnMSk1ByQsUC9/wE)

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 50 bytes

Returns an infinite stream of fibonacci numbers. 1-indexed (starts at 0).

Fast, carries over an accumulator with the sum of the previous two numbers.

```
fn->Stream.unfold{0,1},fn{a,b}->{a,{b,a+b}}end end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYuxDsIgFEV3v@IlLiVSUoeubA5OHfwCsI9IpM8GHomm8u1IHW7OHc7B4N8@1q466vWNI5pFZXKvMG@DPBfpaDPSll43bFaaky0FaYa2KlQn4PDVcKG8KDZP7MZBwBH2C/xAcD4mhnEADLggcdrt66Q8pRXv3NQ1IvOnwRP/k4gpB64/)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 57 bytes

`_=1;i=0;for(z=10;z--;)alert((a=>!(o=_+i)+(i=_)+!(_=o))())`

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```python
i=j=1
while 1:print j;i,j=j+i,i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1Mny9ZQx5CrPCMzJ1XB0KqgKDOvRCHLGiSepZ2pk/n/PwA)

Uses a loop to infinitely print the sequence. <s>Will eventually error out due to integer overflow.</s> It has been pointed out to me that Python uses arbitrary precision integers. Learn something new every day!

Comment: Python uses arbitrary precision integers so an integer overflow will not occur.

Comment: `i,j=1,1` can be `i=j=1`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 19 bytes

```julia
!a=round(φ^a/√5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/9fMc@2KL80L0XjfFtcnv6jjlmmmv8LijLzSjQUjQw0/wMA)

This is 16 chars and 19 bytes, a goof way to abuse Julia beats the existing Julia answers which were 20 bytes. by 1 bytes and 3 chars

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>68</s>, 56 bytes

Lambda using decimal size for single n.

EDIT:  Ty Jo King for pointing out better ways to assign the maths to the vars!

```cs
p=>{decimal a=0,b=1,j=0;for(;j++<p;b=a-b)a+=b;return a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LCoMwFET3fsVdJmhF1zFuCl21ULDQ9c2jEtFE8igU8dutpTKLGc5sjgwn6bzeUjC2h@4Top5YJkcMAe7e9R6nJQOYkxiNhBAx7vV2RsENjSX0dwJckpWN0tJMOBZwjBYU8G3m7XIAQF4VgtfFwCv2cp6wIc@bmQmOJ0Ex54J5HZO3gGzdWPa3Kc/OBjfq8ulN1FdjNVGkrmj5cF30uzWhlGXrnu0L)

Comment: I don't know much about `C++`, but [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7LCoMwFET3fsVdJmhF1zFuCl21ULDQ9c2jEtFE8igU8dutpTKLGc5sjgwn6bzeUjC2h@4Top5YJkcMAe7e9R6nJQOYkxiNhBAx7vV2RsENjSX0dwJckpWN0tJMOBZwjBYU8G3m7XIAQF4VgtfFwCv2cp6wIc@bmQmOJ0Ex54J5HZO3gGzdWPa3Kc/OBjfq8ulN1FdjNVGkrmj5cF30uzWhlGXrnu0L)

Comment: [note that there's already a way shorter answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11379/39244), and that's including a (partial, at least) signature

Answer (score 0):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 7 bytes

```
1c[oca]
```

Not a Fibonacci number, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Golfscript 42 bytes

```
~:n;2 -1?:h;5h?:f;1f+2/:p;p n?-1p*n~)?-f/
```

I origionally solved this in python with 64chars because i didn't think golfscript supported floats. I did some more digging and it actually does if you raise a number to -1.

Back in my graph theory/combinitorics class we went over creating an O(1) form of recurance eqautions, the fibonacci sequence is one example we used. I don't remeber the method for converting a recurance equation to constant time because the class was a few years ago, but I found the solution for the fibonacci equation online

[image: constant time fibonacci sequence]

[image: phi]

This allows you to compute the nth fibbonacci number without computing the previous terms

Comment: You're correct, hardcoing phi is a bit messy, see my updated answer using golfscript and not hardcoding any values

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 57 bytes

```c
x=0,y=1,s;main(){for(;;){s=x+y;printf("%d,",s);x=y;y=s;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/C1kCn0tZQp9g6NzEzT0OzOi2/SMPaWrO62LZCu9K6oCgzryRNQ0k1RUdJp1jTusK20rrStti6tvb/fwA)

Comment: Shouldn't you be starting at `1,1,2,3...`? Also, you can omit the `=0`, and instead of `for(;;)`, you can call `main()` again. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/79Cp9LWUKfYOjcxM09Ds7rYtkK70rqgKDOvJE1DSTVFR0mnwrZS07rSFqbEuvb/fwA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilingcat And even further (assuming no arguments) [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/79Cp9g6NzEzT6NSs7rYtkK70rqgKDOvJE1DSTVFR0mnwrZSEyJfrGld@/8/AA)

Comment: or [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///v8I6NzEzT6NSs7qgKDOvJE1DSTVFR0mnUhMiXqGtUWFbqalpXfv/PwA) with a different interpreter

Answer (score 0):

### [tq](https://github.com/A-ee/tq), 6 bytes

Currently this has no separator...

```
01p+r)
```

### Explanation

```
0,        # Initialize the number 0
  1,      # (Since a preceding 0 in decimal is disallowed)
    p+r,  # Initialize the third item in the list as the 
          # previous item + the previous-previous item
        ) # Extend this forever
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <del>59</del> <del>51</del> <del>55</del> 33 bytes

```python
a=0
b=1
while 1:a,b=b,a+b;print a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9HWgCvJ1pCrPCMzJ1XB0CpRJ8k2SSdRO8m6oCgzr0Qh8f9/AA)

Thanks for @[pppery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46076/pppery) for saving a whole 22 bytes!

Comment: Do it recursively would golf it a lot.

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive Thanks for the idea, but I didn't figure it out how to do it. Do you know how?

Comment: If you do the print before the reassignment you can initialise `a` and `b` on the same line

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>121</s> <s>110</s> <s>86</s> 82 bytes

1-indexed

```
listen to N
X's1
Y's1
while N
let Z be X+Y
let X be Y
let Y be Z
let N be-1

say X
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 0):

#### **x86 machine code - 15 bytes**

This is the easiest way my answer to generate fibonacci numbers. I don't believe using [XADD](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xadd) instruction, I can generate fibonacci numbers. Well, output store in `eax`, debug it using GDB with [peda](https://github.com/longld/peda) (GDB plugin) to make debugging easier. Just make a breakpoint at `fib_seq` label then `s` (mean single-step).

So this is example :

```
     1                                  global fib_seq
     2                                  section .text
     3                                  
     4                                  fib_seq:
     5 00000000 31C0                        xor eax, eax ; eax = 0
     6 00000002 6A01                        push 1
     7 00000004 5A                          pop edx      ; edx = 1
     8 00000005 6A0A                        push 10
     9 00000007 59                          pop ecx  ; loop counter
    10                                  .loop:
    11 00000008 E305                        jecxz .exit_loop
    12 0000000A 0FC1D0                      xadd eax, edx
    13 0000000D E2F9                        loop .loop
    14                                  .exit_loop:
```

Answer (score 0):

## BRASCA, 13 bytes

After being inactive here for god knows how long, I built a little esolang and decided to put it to the test.

Outputs each number seperated by newline.

```
nlo1[:n:R+lo]
```

### Explanation

```
n                   - Output 0 as number (an empty stack always pops zero)
 lo                 - Push 10 (line feed) to the stack and print it
   1                - Push 1 to the stack
    [       ]       - While not zero:
     :n             -   Output the number
       :R+          -   Add it with the previous number
          lo        -   And print another line feed
```

### Language Link

**[Github Repo](https://github.com/SjoerdPennings/BRASCA)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 29 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = 29 bytes.

Outputs fibonacci sequence, separated with space.

- Filename (escaped): `\001.rX\001.w.c.n.c.t.v.m.v.+ .oX.a`

  - Actual: `.rX.w.c.n.c.t.v.m.v.+ .oX.a`
- Content: empty.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRhrW9pI93t/xTAFMkMSkiBWZBhdRdulq9RVt2sF6pOSUKIhARIUCvSvd89MwkXb53nf3Q9kbmfO/TY4dtT/8RqZ5f3dcm@nW7GdSmXvjWPa@/t7lbKzX7a/OHt7FedNxTb3951Xr9Fw6g68Yqk48ILiMIy8qRcNXkVujHR3wiYDO3pAplkqMXc6DMcxOqvfHZ2d8Toj8Wzooq9u3A2DXj4vV91wMLADhx4YjvtoBBPfR6WDvJXPp5cvjq5/5zhLUjikD1cI5BHNzsWgVpfJRF/iFdm/mo2bu6vrE14yzZ3V5sWHq8bN2ae7@ofLy9P6NbdYC@kBwtn58dHV73cfTy@vGh@aVUCDOvn8HEmpQiSlZGKhHrPl@s7tr664g4lvxy6K@uJCOIxh9hSOnWjoezGzfc@OkP4VKdm5peLsb3ipcEWMCmv@dXZWPz/hVUkChBYEHRb1vV4siTtIAKYbbrcfouxrihFHFuosFiSD3EfbRziDerYfuZjm80RCRX0X9BqHIQp9Bx3kSyyDqjShIQGmi8h1kBIZU2NmsAg@3wxFYv4mMSdYACTFsUYB4vmPfH@fgX2Gnu8SSnrcZF07cgG5hZEXINIrUNQDVTM3srvMjiJ38MWfCauGYNCjAOmP8cRaxGOk1yNkWqWd8u6bvco@UlrtoNBRFl/H7hAVF/bTA1KOT981mnPQGBmOvSDuIWV4EX4Iml7jrluPrh4/9t66p@PLp7@nN7NP327to/h6cO6cqHomm8spi/9AMWtyXG9hlDUR7vA2xqAFP3xyxyRKWCA418Va1qQU4TZmmIHqFGlugrF2peEqpswHtTi8/IYt51ctX1U7PGsyr0f8A17K52FLL3U4d/J5IANKq9O5r/MSOyOUSSqo3sqaHbZcnjZP5mJ32ZsE3dgLAwSrucBE5wk/2MfsqS@s4dN0B2F01dJ1v5MiuwFEihRPf0QhmEIaEq/Um9yGQPO9wD0w6TxQudF6ms6@dQzdsA3BeFAzU4K4aKPjMiomAHiBu3aMLPAREYseTNlSwoFkJMFid4xDjH4DrgIV0FUxKAhQhlIOwzHy@UxA5V2pI9ih8wkPdCuVKziYSNCUwxrfsJIwgZ6MEBXtX/LyUpaEOWyn/ADEcink@xcoU1aXYHiWumUuardFkli5O16QFkrUjHQ/RiWRLQDTYmUFm5tiiMAYYC@Y9WFDiQqgsmEYdKPHcdwxCsSuWVQ1Wiq4s56sSxTs405jtjSGxhzQsAiCbRnVLAa/9KgPsz4IHhuFTMYGJ4x4xmj13NQazBZK8e46hmr4gLX5VgcyxAbbAwNdUFQrDCJgADb7YtMYGDocWzBb8cKWFnj@CzF3nompzC9anmpK3x9yMVd1C5x6mPkOTruSwjcEmIiHIXp7haLJlygek6yp7VB2AV7sdTj4r1UjTZ5E2VCztbdXFPIdsDoHeIKzGHaQ3Wp2tAQXZY7ru5CXEwxs2aztAHwkaKUo15OUjyjFhVqfUUcFjDdrXBs2mgcQvkQoAVQAqdJoZXMdcGBBugAfkA/sM@VizWY82RFOPa3N6FTlM53M@BSCnIuw7YVjcg9hf18DMEaHiQbs1j0kDLatFPAxYrRV43CqzqpgnsOpDmMGxgKMORhzsypk85/EFukjoWICFY8lGQKOJQnw4FUpgHAoFrKGsU6Gct/47CNQi2GIMiH0UjAuSJ4y4yuskQHDF6he0mW9O3DanjuOBx1QpZGHnGWwmK1iD7aSYIYDOpcntthcyqkjpiLLiyLVS2scdAWiECki3IhJlcUiWTuAeuzGk3EgMm9CRRUIbMdZUdXFOvoSr9YZsYZSvVq3s2LD8R5XGzkJEK4QREaxYPx9/ZbgPCQr0MoLztblKMmgV60HDn4OsbiqA/2kDihQHONVklCEvhfrq@uM7pJjOn9QVQZoOhw@wmeE1Y4B43FN7LJjVaUw0Y5TAJi8QC5YBwJU1jkHQT6iDKIw6o69YcxTRsETI9d1vuMiptEYWiy53C4vF@SECnm0Pwjt8BPJE7C2ATiF@pOoP/PHs8L0fn2A4ODA2jr6Y3MkpdmcXD87EURlilif35BLOr/kACY50fXU9OhyC2hC6mn6JrpVq@fz9Vpp9w09rEOp2QJ7J3CBBibBd6NoCLSTgE0CDkAbpOlsXQ0Ps2ZV35blL0EMbtW39o7I@ap@HFWxdr5dNZLtzKZ8rG8NQfYkKDKgVDohN/DdOg@TSv/rw4A0tJF2ovkbmPmIAxD0Hr4bfI37ZESlFzWgPjRq3GcN8KEJISc8zbEjraFZlH7HLVPf7@DDE7VcqZZ3gcqGjAc8XJB3z2nfkXOtrt1qn@j8nOPiXRU1w1gkKferO8aszgGe3QJZQZ4xyWF5LzHMboV@Gbv2g0iK9e/4c7m1s9vJYjq/5eWyXk8vJyCiMJNKcs8qQzGqc74jCmACBO@C2AsmLlsK/SfQ9Vq5IgAPdvcolduShw31hAD9xD8hUtcBmAmDsgtyW/i0LWN3S/kX5Pq5AqKtw5tnQfAIZrnXPlKZdUH1JkT8PZduDUa4B118FAGsNTpMDqI1FJP7ZH2v6x3@cdsA4y1SYjKG10kY@LN8HngSrdARwcVxFcEUCzFEEMjApgXhMc@M@bQJNkAHqQggMoBii/8p@VMbJRQhnmkKbbE/pWslDpZu/lkbbV2c/YuLB9sXv62ZIsnVFV8p@2vAeEsTfZEpn2t@kBw/iH66DyYTINvnjrDMNkhaKgUce4DE8sxiMk01RO5VIR8REToFci@/SUakNDEblyDCnhtSshAJSu@l8wCf6ovoFaWpsQaBCAPCAKILsJp5qDeqjWeWk6XrGcbCC4yilo3SbPA@9RUi1Q4s@3Lkqbdkq@jWHYeZtb@MDvzDkeFXfWNE6TZVqIf/J87cL3HmAGdO4hTF/cfb5tH5KVfapmkVxzdyeCp2iwH84uJjcQA/FRXDm6KtvKp/aF6fNq@5ovxIKxzOyvt4kb4@Ue/V@iSF3px1X7289dRFehcy8i8u/Xwk77SDNcj24Vo9PTDJ@mG6he6/vTqbl0g83KBXVhaR@PdCf0BWMNasVYv2WabpAmqTYqFNs9CJtS3Rm9AlhoeIqONcdlB6F8m/VyYiDYQD0a7A5vinzQ2bThnpzfIzANGnRHAeoqHnaG7sDVxt2B1OtMfoG3Ps2KXbYpb/t5ix7flID8qllTggBCm255X2UgjTtgxl8zbSS1Z5r1zZeVOuwCsCXiugFdnLJu2rnby9/r2exYsr0ZMYsHiwrTokvAIY8bYixg@XV@B8qw5PJAcP2jFPdBYMXjK024Inwfo/gXY7F2LNg4iEXlO2WWmrPUK4HYB54G7SCSRtQNIOwIPiMrdrcm6lkkUIr/wJjeBSenuZHneTfwWEJn4mAU/8qI/06Mc/)

### With comments

```
XX.z
# push 1; push $(($(pop)*$(rand)))
# NOTE rand pushes 0<=x<1
# NOTE null character cannot be used for filename
.a\001.rXX.z
# push 1; push 88; while [ $(pop) -ne 0 ]; do
.aX\001.wXX.z
  # Do I really need to explain more?
  # Just read the specification; I am going to bed
  # also a sequence .t.v.m.v is an idiom
  # to move top item to bottom
  .a.c.n.c.t.v.m.v.+ .oX.a
```

Answer (score 0):

## VBScript, 41 bytes

```
sub f(x,y):msgbox x:f y,x+y:end sub:f 1,1
```

Very simple self-explanatory recursive function.

It outputs its first parameters and recursively called again with the second parameter and first+second parameter. And first it is called with 1,1.

```
1,1 -> 1, f(1,2)
1,2 -> 1, f(2,3)
2,3 -> 2, f(3,5)
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 9 bytes

```
+s[p+~$]0
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%2Bs%5Bp%2B%7E%24%5D100&inputs=)

Note: the link only runs this loop 100 times instead of infinitely because the online interpreter behaves strangely with an infinite loop for this code (which is a problem with the website, not the interpreter).

## Explanation

```
+s           increment the top of the stack (to 1) and save to memory
  [    ]0    infinite loop
   p         print top of stack
    +~       increment top of stack by the value in storage
      $      swap the value on top of the stack with the value in storage
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP 4 (58 chars)

The function **f** will print *$n* Fibonacci numbers.
If *$n* = 0 **f** will take it for Infinity, then reach the PHP floating point limit and print NAN forever.

```php
function f($n){for($i=!$j=0;$n-=print' '.$j=-$j+$i+=$j;);}
```

### PHP with GMP (70 chars)

If [GMP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php) is available, it allow for arbitrary-length integers to be worked with.
So we can compute `f(1e5)`, output will be *1,045,063,704* chars long with no precision loss.

```php
function f($n){for($i=!$j=0;$n-=print' '.$i=gmp_add($k=$i,$j);$j=$k);}
```

**Info:** `f(1e5)` = `25974...46875` has 20,899 digits.

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 48 bytes

```
proc f(n:int):int=(if n<=2:1 else:f(n-1)+f(n-2))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY3DQqK8pMV0jTyrDLzSjRBhK1GZppCno2tkZWhQmpOcaoVUFLXUFMbRBlpakL0QbXDjAEA)

Bytes counted using `wc -c`. This is the standard recursive function approach, as opposed to the iterative full program of my other [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence/230667#230667).

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 1 byte

```
f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/x@IzAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [SunSip](https://github.com/TvoozMagnificent/SunSip) `-w -n`, 298 bytes

(just means disable warnings and newlines)

```
set a to
defined
set 5 to 5
calc multiplication 5 last
skip
set to "
in
calc int last
recurse
out
set to 1
calc greater a last
calc multiplication 5 last
skip
set to 1
exit



set 1 to 1
calc subtraction a 1
recurse
set b to
calc subtraction a 1
calc subtraction last 1
recurse
calc addition last b
```

A big fat 298 bytes but I'm still proud.

Syntax Highlighted:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 8 bytes

This is straight from the J-uby README.

```ruby
:++[0,1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWK6y0taMNdAxjIdzlBQpu0YYGUN6CBRAaAA)

### Explanation

From the README:

> `(F+init).(n)` starts an array with init, then applies `F` to the last `init.length` entries `n` times

In this case, `init` is `[0,1]` and `F` is `:+`, i.e. add.

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 39 bytes

```
31p132p>31g32g:.+ v
       ^,p23p13g23<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//83NiwwNDYqsDM2TDc2SrfS01Yo41KAgDidAiNjoGy6kbHN//8A)

I'll throw this into my Seed generator and see if it gives me anything good.

Answer (score 0):

## [Headass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass), 26 bytes

```
UODONOE.U)UP:R-OU^[U]ODONE
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVU9ET05PRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUiLCIiLCIxMSIsIiJd) - 1 indexed

Just realized I hadn't done this challenge after doing a fibonacci related code challenge. This code is just ripped from a section of [my answer to that question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264582/107310).

#### Explanation:

```
UODONOE.  code block 0
UO        i = input
  DO      a = 0
    NO    b = 1
      E   go to code block b (1)
       .  end code block

U)UP:R-OU^[U]ODONE  code block 1
U)  :           NE  while(i){
     R-O              i--
        U^            r1 = a
          [           r2 = a
           U]O         a = b + r2
              DO       b = r1
                NE  } (go to code block 1)
  UP                print a
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 31 bytes

```swift
var f={$0<2 ?1:f($0-1)+f($0-2)}
```