# Tips for code-golfing in C#

Tags: code-golf, tips, c#

What general tips do you have for golfing in C#? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to C# (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

-- borrowed from marcog's idea ;)

Comment: Forgive me for the picture of a calendar, it was all I could find on short notice.

Answer (score 67):

Instead of using `.ToString()` use `+""` for numerics and other types that can be natively cast to a string safely.

```
.ToString() <-- 11 chars
+""         <--  3 chars
```

Comment: This also works in JS.

Comment: @Cyoce And Java

Comment: This is usually actually 5 chars if you need to use the string afterwards for including the braces... `(1+"").DoSomethingWith1String();`

Comment: If you need the string you're usually storing it. Just about any other usage can natively infer the ToString()...

Comment: Note that this actually calls the static `String.Concat(object)` with the argument, rather than the virtual calling `object.ToString()`. `Concat` explicitly converts `null` to the empty string ([see the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,a17e32697e4baaf6)). There is no 'native casting' going on, you can convert anything like this, it's just that the result might not be very useful in some cases! (but the null behaviour may well be).

Comment: Alternative - [string interpolation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation): ```$"{n}"```

Comment: Yah, that just recently got added tho, compared to the 2011 post date.

Comment: @jcolebrand how about something like .ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")!???

Answer (score 46):

I once deliberately placed my program in `namespace System` so I can shorten access to a specific class. Compare

```
using System;using M=System.Math;
```

to

```
namespace System{using M=Math;
```

Comment: Just remember that it is better to fully qualify classes/functions when a single use solves the problem.  This is only useful if you have to call something more than once, and even then only for items in the `System` namespace.

Comment: You can also just do `using System;class P...`.

Comment: @Logan: This wasn't about just `using System;` but also about having an alias for a class in the same namespace, which is shorter the way I've shown here.

Comment: It's even shorter to do `using static System.Math;` in C#6 (add you can use any of those functions as if they were truly global--not in a class). The original suggestion may still be shorter than `using static` if you need to access multiple classes.

Comment: @milk: the additional `static` keyword often is longer than any savings from leaving out `M.` on the method calls, but yes, it's an option, but it comes at a hefty upfront cost that needs lots of calls to amortise.

Answer (score 34):

If using LINQ you can pass a method directly to `Select` instead of making a lambda.

So, instead of

```
foo.Select(x=>int.Parse(x))
```

you can use

```
foo.Select(int.Parse)
```

directly.

(Discovered recently when improving on one of [Timwi's C# answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/numbers-sums-products/1181#1181).)

Comment: FWITW this is called *η-reduction*

Comment: It's also known as [*"point free" style*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944446/what-is-point-free-style-in-functional-programming)

Comment: To the more pragmatic of us, it's simply _shorter_ :-þ

Comment: Interesting! Would love to learn more. I asked a question over at [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/411287/what-is-point-free-aka-%ce%b7-reduction-or-pointless-and-how-can-it-be-used-in-c) @ThreeFx

Answer (score 32):

Use `var` for declaring and initializing (single) variables to save characters on the type:

```
string x="abc";
```

becomes

```
var x="abc";
```

Isn't particulaly necessary for `int`, of course.

Comment: Remember that `var` cannot have multiple declarators, for example `var x="x",y="y";` is not possible.

Answer (score 28):

Remember that the smallest compilable program in C# is 29 characters:

```
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {   
    }
}
```

So start by removing that from your length and judge your answer on how much over that it takes.  C# cannot compete with other languages when it comes to printing or reading input, which is the heart of most `[code-golf]` problems, so don't worry about that.  As a C# golfer, you're really competing against the language.

A few other things to keep in mind:

- Reduce all loops and `if` statements
  to a single line if possible in order
  to remove the brackets.
- If given the option between stdin and
  command line, always use command
  line!

Comment: This does usually involve ternary as well ;)

Comment: `As a C# golfer, you're really competing against the language` [Unbelievably related](https://www.oracle.com/java/index.html)

Comment: Actually, that's not true. It compiles using `static int Main()` as well, which would be 28 characters.

Comment: @Metoniem [That requires a `return` something](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv3/PzknsbhYIaC6uCSxJDNZITOvRME3MTNPQ7O6tvb///96AA).

Comment: Be advised that starting with C# 9 you can use top-level statements thus making the smallest compilable program exactly 0 bytes (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements)

Answer (score 26):

Instead of

```
bool a = true;
bool b = false;
```

do

```
var a=0<1;
var b=1<0;
```

If you need multiple variables, use this (suggested by [@VisualMelon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26981/visualmelon))

```
bool a=0<1,b=!a;
```

Comment: Note that if you need multiple variables of the same type it is usually cheaper to declare the type a comma separate the declarations `bool a=0<1,b=!a;`

Answer (score 23):

When reading each character of a command line argument, rather than looping up to the string's length:

```
static void Main(string[]a){
    for(int i=0;i<a[0].Length;)Console.Write(a[0][i++]);
}
```

You can save a character by using a try/catch block to find the end:

```
static void Main(string[]a){
    try{for(int i=0;;)Console.Write(a[0][i++]);}catch{}
}
```

This applies to any array within an array such as:

- `string[]`
- `int[][]`
- `IList<IList<T>>`

Comment: That is truly horrifying... I love it!

Comment: holy crap this is genius, I actually just saved a character while looping an array

Comment: This is truly evil!

Answer (score 20):

If you need to use `Console.ReadLine()` multiple times in your code (min 3 times), you could do:

```
Func<string>r=Console.ReadLine;
```

and then just use

```
r()
```

instead

Comment: I think you need to remove `()` from the first line.

Comment: @mellamokb that's right, thanks! fixed.

Comment: Can't you do `auto r=Console.ReadLine;`?

Comment: @claudiu no, unfortunally not http://ideone.com/jFsVPX

Comment: @Claudiu, `auto` is a `C++` verb. `var` is for `C#`. The reason this can't be done is because `Console.ReadLine` is overloaded so the function signature needs to be specified in order to tell the compiler which overload is wanted.

Comment: You can do `var r=Console.ReadLine;` and `var s=(int x)=>x*x;` since [C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/lambda-improvements#var)

Answer (score 18):

Favor the ternary operator over `if`..`else` blocks where appropriate.

For example:

```
if(i<1)
    j=1;
else
    j=0;
```

is more efficiently:

```
j=i<1?1:0;
```

Comment: Am I the only one that feels that the second case is inherently more readable for things like this in general? I do that routinely. In addition, if I need to avoid a null condition (like on a string) I do something like `var x = input ?? "";` (I loves my coalesces)

Comment: There are times when it is far from being the more readable option, particularly when `i < 1` is a complex statement or when the name of `j` is long.  IMO, it also fails to convey side effects very well.  In the case where `if (i < 1)` is something like `if (SendEmail(recipient))` which returns true/false depending on the success of the side effects, I prefer the if/then notation.

Comment: @NickLarsen I meant only on simple assignments, I should have clarified. Yes, for things which may have side effects or which may call functions as the (1:0) spot, I don't prefer the short way, I agree with you and prefer the long way. But for defining defaults of the order `int value; if (boolean == true) {value = 1;}else{value=2;}` in that style I prefer the ternary. ~~ Anyways, I know this has been gone over time and time again on the intertubes ;)

Comment: No need for parentheses in the second case - `j=i<1?1:0;` is enough.

Comment: The question asks for tips which are somewhat specific to C#. This is one included in the [tips for all languages](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5315/194).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I answered this question over 3 years ago, well before the thread you linked was created

Answer (score 17):

### Effective use of using

You can [replace](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26962/linear-function-solver-from-two-points-x-y/26976#26976) `float` (which is an alias for `System.Single`) with `z` using `z=System.Single;`

Then replace `z=System.Single;` with `z=Single;` by placing the program in the namespace `System`. (As with Joey's answer)

This can be applied for other value types (use what they are an alias for), structs and classes

Answer (score 16):

## LINQ

Instead of using:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,y).Select(i=>f(i))
```

to get an Enumerable with the result of function `f` for every `int` in `[0,y]` you can use

```
new int[y].Select((_,i)=>f(i))
```

if you need `string` or anything that implements `Enumerable` in your program you can use them too

```
var s="I need this anyway";
s.Select((_,i)=>f(i))
```

Comment: I use this trick in my [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84779/shamirs-secret-sharing/84789#84789) for the [Shamir's Secret Sharing](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84779/shamirs-secret-sharing/84789) challenge.

Comment: I don't think that the string part will execute if you don't iterate the ienumerable with optimization on. Just failed for me until I did .ToArray();. Other than that, amazing tip!

Comment: Yes enumerables are lazy but that is true for all three examples not just the one with the string.

Answer (score 15):

In C#, we are not allowed to do `if(n%2)` to check if `n` is a even number. If we do, we get a `cannot implicity convert int to bool`. A naive handling would be to do:

```
if(n%2==0)
```

A better way is to use:

```
if(n%2<1)
```

I used this to gain one byte [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84369/15214).

note that this only works for positive numbers, as `-1%2==-1`, it is considered even with this method.

Answer (score 14):

## Use lambdas to define a function in C# 6

In C# 6, you can use a lambda to define a function:

```
int s(int a,int b)=>a+b;
```

This is shorter than defining a function like this:

```
int s(int a,int b){return a+b;}
```

Comment: C#6 gives a whole new range of ability to code-golf

Comment: In C#7, this can be done inside another function to create local functions. I doubt this will help while golfing, but it's still just a neat trick to know.

Comment: That's not formally a lambda.  It's an [expression bodied member](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members).

Answer (score 11):

Looping:

Variable declarations:

```
int max;
for(int i=1;i<max;i++){
}
```

become:

```
int max,i=1;
for(;i<max;i++){
}
```

And if you have a need to or work with the i variable only once, you could start at -1 (or 0 depending on the loop circumstance) and increment inline:

```
int max,i=1;
for(;i<max;i++){
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

to

```
int max,i=1;
for(;i<max;){
  Console.WriteLine(++i);
}
```

And that reduces by one character, and slightly obfuscates the code as well. Only do that to the FIRST `i` reference, like thus: (granted one character optimizations aren't much, but they can help)

```
int max,i=1;
for(;i<max;i++){
  Console.WriteLine(i + " " + i);
}
```

to

```
int max,i=1;
for(;i<max;){
  Console.WriteLine(++i + " " + i);
}
```

---

when the loop does not have to increment `i` (reverse order loop):

```
for(int i=MAX;--i>0;){
      Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: I usually put the `++` in such cases directly into the loop header: `for(;++i<max;)` which is both easier to follow and harder to get wrong.

Comment: @Joey In those cases I tend to switch to while(++i<max) which is the same length but easier to read.

Comment: ICR: depends on whether you can put another (earlier) statement into the `for` header as well, which would then save a character again.

Comment: You can move both declarations back into the for clause for a1 byte savings.

Comment: I like changing `for(;i<max;)` to `while(i<max)`. Same number of bytes, but for me it just looks cleaner.

Comment: Okay so change it?

Comment: If you won't need the variable again, you can use:  while(max-->0) { foo;}

Answer (score 11):

If you need to use a generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` at least two times in your code, you could declare a dictionary class, like in this example:

```
class D:Dictionary<int,string>{}
```

and then just use

```
D d=new D{{1,"something"},{2,"something else"}};
```

instead of repeating `Dictionary<int,string>` for every instantiation.

I have used this technique in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5509/3527)

Comment: And also "D d" instead of "var d"

Comment: @Zukki Obviously! What was I thinking? :)

Comment: Alternative: ```using D = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,string>;```

Answer (score 10):

For one-line lambda expressions, you can skip the brackets and semicolon. For one-parameter expressions, you can skip the parentheses.

Instead of

```
SomeCall((x)=>{DoSomething();});
```

Use

```
SomeCall(x=>DoSomething);
```

Comment: I never write the parentheses for one-parameter lambdas, even on production code.

Comment: I always use the brackets because I like to split the lambda into multiple lines for readability.

Comment: `SomeCall(DoSomething)` is even better

Answer (score 10):

You can use `float` and `double` literals to save a few bytes.

```
var x=2.0;
var y=2d;         // saves 1 byte
```

When you need some `int` arithmetic to return a `float` or `double` you can use the literals to force the conversion.

```
((float)a+b)/2;  // this is no good
(a+b)/2.0;       // better
(a+b)/2f;        // best
```

If you ever run into a situation where you have to to cast you can save a few bytes by using multiplication instead.

```
((double)x-y)/(x*y);
(x*1d-y)/(x*y);      // saves 5 bytes
```

Comment: Even shorter: `(x-y)*1d/x/y;`

Answer (score 9):

Remember where private or public are inherent, such as the following:

```
class Default{static void Main()
```

as compared to

```
public class Default { public static void Main()
```

Comment: And always make the class one letter only :-)

Comment: Oh, and another nice thing, implied here: `Main` does not need any arguments in contrast to Java, for example.

Comment: @Joey: and neither does it need to be public.

Comment: @martinho ~ did you read my answer? ;) no public on main

Comment: @Joey ~ I was trying to keep it to one per post ;) ... figured someone else would post taht about main or classes only being one letter. Seeing as how nobody else has, I'll go ahead and add that one too.

Comment: @drachenstern: I was constrasting it with Java, where you are forced to bow to the full signature: `public static void main(String[] a)`.

Comment: Ohhh good point @Martinho

Comment: The example is wrong. Classes are `internal` by default, not `public`. Members are `private` by default, not `public`.

Comment: @KendallFrey, I think the point was that `Main` is a special case or doesn't need to be `public`?

Answer (score 9):

There are circumstances when an output parameter can save characters. Here's a *slightly* contrived example, a 10 pin bowling score algorithm.

With a return statement:

```
........10........20........30........40........50........60........70........80........90.......100.......110.......120.......130.......140.......150..
public double c(int[]b){int n,v,i=0,X=10;double t=0;while(i<19){n=b[i]+b[i+1];v=b[i+2];t+=(n<X)?n:X+v;if(b[i]>9)t+=b[i+(i>16|v!=X?3:4)];i+=2;}return t;}
```

And with an output parameter:

```
........10........20........30........40........50........60........70........80........90.......100.......110.......120.......130.......140.......
public void d(int[]b,out double t){int n,v,i=0,X=10;t=0;while(i<19){n=b[i]+b[i+1];v=b[i+2];t+=(n<X)?n:X+v;if(b[i]>9)t+=b[i+(i>16|v!=X?3:4)];i+=2;}}
```

The output parameter here saves a total of 5 characters.

Answer (score 9):

## Avoid single-statement `foreach` loops

If the loop's statement returns a non-`int` (including `void`!) "value", it can be replaced  with LINQ:

```
foreach(var x in a)Console.WriteLine(F(x));
a.Any(x=>Console.WriteLine(F(x))is int);
```

If the value happens to be an `int`, you can use a condition that will always be true or always be false (for example, `>0` or `<n`), a different type and/or `All` instead of `Any`.

Comment: `is GC` saves 1 byte

Answer (score 9):

## Use `dynamic` to group declarations

`dynamic` is a forgotten feature that literally performs dynamic typing in C#! It has limitations (doesn't support extension methods, is bad at inferring that you want to use it, ...), but can often save bytes by merging declarations of incompatible types. Compare the following:

```
var a=[something of type IEnumerable<int>];var b=[something of type string];int i=x+~y^z
dynamic a=[something of type IEnumerable<int>],b=[something of type string],i=x+~y^z
```

That's 4 bytes of savings!

Comment: One of the best tips on the page.

Comment: With C# 7, you can sometimes save another byte with tuples: `var(a,i)=([...],[...])`.

Answer (score 8):

## Use the weird kind of the `is` operator

`a is var b` *always* defines the variable `b` equal to `a` and returns `true`. It is unclear how have the humans who design C# come up with this (inline variable declarations that return `true` for some reason seem to be beyond Javascript to me), but it works.
It can sometimes be used to shorten code (this is an oversimplified example; savings can often be smaller or zero):

```
a=>{var b=f(a);return g(b,b);}
a=>g(f(a)is var b?b:b,b)
```

Answer (score 7):

### String Interpolation

A really simple space-saving improvement is interpolation. Instead of:

```
string.Format("The value is ({0})", (method >> 4) + 8)
```

just use `$` to inline expressions:

```
$"The value is ({(method >> 4) + 8})"
```

This, together with the new expression bodies in C#6.0 should make any simple string-calculation challenge pretty golfable in C#.

Comment: Also note that `i+$" bottles of beer";` is shorter than `$"{i} bottles of beer"`.

Comment: @aloisdg In that first case you should leave `$` out, though.

Comment: @Metoniem Indeed! I let it because in my original case I had two `{i}` one in front and one in the middle ;)

Comment: @aloisdg Ahh, I see. Yeah, shame comments can't be edited :(

Answer (score 7):

If you need to include multiple `using`s that all fall off of the same hierarchy it is often shorter to use the longest one as the `namespace`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
//Some code
```

vs:

```
namespace System.Linq
{
    //Some code
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The [`Compute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_DataTable_Compute_System_String_System_String_) instance method of `System.Data.DataTable`, allows to evaluate a simple string expression, e.g. :

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 166 bytes

```cs
namespace System.Data
{
    class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write(new DataTable().Compute("30*2+50*5/4",""));
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYw/C8IwFMT3fIqQKakai9qpY10FQcH5Gd8QyJ/ii4pIP3tsLNTfcBx3xxlaGTI5B/BIPRjkpzcl9HoPCdiH8RHjgIgff35KCpQgWcOf0d74AWyQaq7@o0IXA0WH@nK3CWXAFy/fZ7g6lEp30fePMRfbutosmrpq1juxFEKpdn4Z2KRDzl8)

Not very "golfy" per se, but sometimes might be useful.

Answer (score 7):

## Swapping two variables

Normally, to swap two variables, you have to declare a temporary variable to store the value. It would look like something along the lines of this:

```
var c=a;a=b;b=c;
```

That's 16 bytes! There are some other methods of swapping that are better.

```
//Using tuples
(a,b)=(b,a);
//Bitwise xoring 
a=a^b^(b=a);
//Addition and subtraction
a=a+b-(b=a);
//Multiplication and division
a=a*b/(b=a);
```

The last three only work for numeric values, and as ASCII-only pointed out, the last two might result in an ArithmeticOverflow exception. All of the above are 12 bytes, a 4 byte saving compared to the first example.

Comment: Only applies for numbers though, and even then anything other than tuples and xor risk running into integer limits of you're applying this to integers. Occasionally, other number types will run into limits too

Answer (score 6):

Use C# lambda. Since PPCG allows lambda for input/output we should use them.

A classic C# methods looks like this:

```
bool Has(string s, char c)
{
    return s.Contains(c);
}
```

As a lambda, we will write

```
Func<string, char, bool> Has = (s, c) => s.Contains(c);
```

Anonymous lambda are allowed too:

```
(s, c) => s.Contains(c)
```

Remove all the noise and focus!

Update:

We can improve one step more with [currying](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rmcochran/functional-programming-in-C-Sharp-currying/) as @TheLethalCoder comment:

```
s => c => s.Contains(c);
```

Example of curring by @Felix Palmen: [How compute WPA key?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145763/15214)

It will be helpful when you have exactly 2 parameters, then a empty unused variable `_` will be better. See [meta post about this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12681/15214). I use this trick [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153236/15214). You will have to change a bit the function. Example: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BSgMxFEX3@YrHbJoQDbqUNKUyC6FYKszCpcTXqK/GxCavBSnz7WN0U3F5L/dyDtZLzCVMh0rpFYavyuHDir/J9DnGgEw5VXMXUiiE/xb3lPZWYPS1wsNJAFT2TAi3v6/55nnX/gsY2FPpfQ3gYHpyi9PRF2DXdfYlF4lvLaGbLWdWa5zfXFvWDlXfsDkG81iIQwMFWbk0tlllShJ1112wGd7pU14ppVHZcbLirHDMtIW1b1MFP2ZwtpDpEKOyrRzFOH0D)

Comment: Not sure if it's anywhere else in the tips but for this example you can use currying too... `s=>c=>...`

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Indeed we can! I will update the answer thank you!

Comment: Can you use eta-reduction in this case? Something like this: `s=>s.Contains`.

Comment: Note that C# and Java answers of the 'untyped lambda' variety are falling out of favour, you might wish to join the discussion on [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11224/26981). The suggested alternative is `(string s,char c)=>s.Contains(c)`

Comment: Discussion about [unamed functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9031/unnamed-functions-in-code-golf)

Comment: With the release of C#9, you will be able to use [top-level statements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#top-level-statements) to save even more bytes if your code does not accept any input.

Answer (score 6):

## Use .NET 6 Top Level Statements, File-Scoped Namespaces, and target-typed new()

Upgrade to .net 6 and you can use single file programs with no boilerplate. You can also use file-scoped namespaces like so:

`namespace whatever;`

Also, when you instantiate an object, if it's type can be inferred by the compiler, you can use a target-typed `new()` constructor. e.g.,

```
class C {}
C c=new();
```

See (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements)

See Also (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/file-scoped-namespaces)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice tip!

Answer (score 5):

Make classnames only one letter. Enhancing on [Tips for code-golfing in C#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c/175#175) we go from

```
class Default{static void Main()
```

to

```
class D{static void Main()
```

which knocks out another 6 chars in this case.

Comment: ditto with variable names

Comment: How is this "at least somewhat specific to C#"?

Answer (score 4):

Using LinqPad will give you the possibility to remove all the program overhead as you can execute statements directly. (And it should be fully legal in codegolf... No one says you need an .exe)

Output is done using the `.Dump()` extension method.

Comment: .NetFiddle support `.Dump()` ;)

Comment: Could you explain it a bit more?

Answer (score 4):

Use the one character non-short-circuiting variants of logical operators where possible:

- `i>0||i<42`
- `i>0|i<42`

or

- `i>0&&i<42`
- `i>0&i<42`

The difference between the two are one byte (yeah!) and the short-circuit principle. In our first example if `i>0` is `true`, `i<42` wont be checked. We dont need it. With the bitwise, both will be evaluated.

example: [Code golf to make logos for New Stack exchange sites](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84898/15214)

Learn more about them on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

Comment: Your statement about short circuiting is incorrect, logical or (||) does indeed short circuit if the left operand is true. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx

Comment: @Phaeze Indeed I wrote the wrong one. Thank you.

Comment: Technically none of these are bitwise operators, they are just non-short-circuiting Boolean operators, because they are operating on Booleans.

Comment: @VisualMelon MSDN uses "logical or bitwise OR" for "x | y" and "logical OR" for "x || y". What should I use?

Comment: These are 'logical' (Boolean being the logic system). Bitwise would be for integer types. I like to make the distinction clear because the a lot of C# golfing can end up being a mix of both, and operator precedence can be a real pain (though they are the same for each type)

Comment: @VisualMelon I am not sure about what to write. Can you made a edit on my answer? Thank you for the comments!

Answer (score 4):

Use `Action` like `Func` to set a function to a variable. `Action` returns nothing (`void`) so it is great for printing.

For example:

```
Action<string>w=Console.WriteLine;
w("Hello World");
```

This tips is inspired by @W0lf [great example of use of `Func` with `ReadLine`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5507/15214).

Answer (score 4):

## Declare empty/matching strings together

If you need to declare multiple empty/matching strings, you can save a few bytes with the following:

```
string a="";string b="";string c=""; // 36 bytes
var a="";var b="";var c="";          // 27 bytes
string a="",b="",c="";               // 22 bytes
string a="",b=a,c=a;                 // 20 bytes
```

Unfortunately `var a="",b=a,c=a;` is illegal, as `implicitly type variable cannot have multiple declarators`

Comment: Can you do `var a=b=c=""` like in javascript?

Comment: @corvus_192 nope - unfortunately not.

Answer (score 4):

*(A particular case of [knowing your operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)!)*

Use `%` for tight-binding (somewhat) limited subtraction. This can save you a pair of parentheses around a subtraction, the result of which you want to multiply or divide by something; but be careful, it has serious limitations.

Instead of

```cs
char b='5'; // b is some ASCII input
int a=(b-48)*c; // we want to find the numerical value of b, and multiply it by something ('0'==48)
```

Consider

```cs
char b='5'; // b is some ASCII input
int a=b%48*c; // only good for ASCII within 48 of '0' (positive only)!
```

Examples:

```cs
'5'%'0'*2 -> 10
'5'%'0'*-1 -> -5
'5'%'0'/2 -> 2
```

I've only just discovered this, and I feel like it will be valuable thing to remember whenever working with ASCII in the future. (I'm currently golfing somewhere where I'm using ASCII for compact numeric representations, but needs to multiply by `1` or `-1` based on another condition, and this striped 2 bytes)

Answer (score 4):

If you're already using Linq in your answer and need to check for a none empty collection use `Any()`. Compare it to the following:

```
Count()>0
Length>0
Count>0
Any()
```

Answer (score 4):

## Use Ranges and indices (C# 8)

You can use the type Index, which can be used for indexing. You can create one from an int that counts from the beginning, or with a prefix ^ operator that counts from the end:

```cs
Index i1 = 3;  // number 3 from beginning
Index i2 = ^4; // number 4 from end
int[] a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
Console.WriteLine($"{a[i1]}, {a[i2]}"); // "3, 6"
```

You can also use a Range type, which consists of two Indexes, one for the start and one for the end, and can be written with a x..y range expression. You can then index with a Range in order to produce a slice:

```cs
var slice = a[i1..i2]; // { 3, 4, 5 }
```

[source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/12/building-c-8-0/)

Answer (score 4):

## [C# Interactive Window](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window)

AKA [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](https://tio.run/#cs-csi) on Try it Online

[image: C# Interactive]

This is a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) for the C# language that includes many advantages to code golfing over using the traditional C# compiler.

Currently, the shortest full program to print `Hello, World!` using the traditional C# compiler is [67 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55445/8340):

```
class P{static void Main(){System.Console.Write("Hello, World!");}}
```

Using the C# Interactive Window, you can do the same thing in [22 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179286/8340):

```
Write("Hello, World!")
```

And yes, I added my answer just for this post ;)

As you can see, ceremonial class definitions are not required. Also, a whole bunch of references are included by default. The [current list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/roslyn/master/src/Interactive/csi/csi.desktop.rsp) is as follows:

- /r:System
- /r:System.Core
- /r:Microsoft.CSharp
- /u:System
- /u:System.IO
- /u:System.Collections.Generic
- /u:System.Console
- /u:System.Diagnostics
- /u:System.Dynamic
- /u:System.Linq
- /u:System.Linq.Expressions
- /u:System.Text
- /u:System.Threading.Tasks

The `System.Linq` namespace is particularly handy as it allows you to write functional style programming which often saves many bytes. Many of the older C# answers added 18 bytes or so for this advantage, simply to import the library `using System.Linq;`. There are other hacks where solutions created their class in the `System` namespace to more succinctly access the `Console` object. None of this is needed with the C# Interactive Window.

Answer (score 4):

## Group statements via tuples

Let's assume the simplest case: you have two statements that return a value and would like to group them into one that returns the second value (perhaps the first one has useful side effects):

```
(s1,o:s2).o
```

This can be used along with inline variable declarations via `is`:

```
(s1 is var x,o:f(x,g(x))).o
```

It also works with the `void -> value` transformation via `is int` (although it doesn't always help):

```
(Print(x)is int,o:f(x)).o
```

Comment: `(s1 is var x,o:f(x,g(x))).o` can usually be shortened to `(s1 is{}x,o:f(x,g(x))).o` now.

Answer (score 3):

Discovered tonight "in the trenches" while improving some golf code... if you have a class for your processing, you can do the work in the constructor to save declaring a method.

I discovered this while reducing a console application - as there was a `static void Main()`, all functions and variables had to be declared static. I created a nested class with member functions and variables, with the main work performed in the constructor.  This also saves characters in the calling code.

e.g. Class with method:

```
class a
{
    public void b()
    {
        new c().d("input");
    }
}
class c
{
    public void d(string e)
    {
        System.Console.Write(e.Replace("in", "out"));
    }
}
```

Class with work in the constructor:

```
class a
{
    public void b()
    {
        new c("input");
    }
}
class c
{
    public c(string e)
    {
        System.Console.Write(e.Replace("in", "out"));
    }
}
```

This example saves 9 characters.

Answer (score 3):

When to use a space and when you can remove it.

After `[]`

- `int[] f(char[] a){Console.Write('a');}`
- `int[]f(char[]a){Console.Write('a');}`

---

Before `$`

- `return $"{a}"`
- `return$"{a}"`

example: [Code golf to make logos for New Stack exchange sites](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84898/15214)

---

(Add yours in comment I will edit)

Answer (score 3):

When you want to join something to output a `string` without delimiter, you should use `string.Concat()`, instead of `string.Join("",)`;

- `string.Join("",)`
- `string.Concat()`

One byte free!

example: [Code golf to make logos for New Stack exchange sites](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84898/15214)

Also `Concat()` has a lot more signatures than `Join`. Check them on MSDN: [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use an `enum` for a method it is often shorter to cast an `int` to it rather than using the value directly:

```
DayOfWeek.Sunday
(DayOfWeek)0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Always use the alias for a type if you need to type as they are usually shorter than the full names. It also means you don't need to include

```
using System;
```

or fully qualify the type when you otherwise wouldn't need to.

For a full list of the aliases visit this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215422/4631427):

```
object:  System.Object
string:  System.String
bool:    System.Boolean
byte:    System.Byte
sbyte:   System.SByte
short:   System.Int16
ushort:  System.UInt16
int:     System.Int32
uint:    System.UInt32
long:    System.Int64
ulong:   System.UInt64
float:   System.Single
double:  System.Double
decimal: System.Decimal
char:    System.Char
```

Note that you can also use the alias for calling static methods, consider:

```
System.String.Concat();
```

vs

```
string.Concat();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're already using Linq in your code and need to create a list use the following:

```
var l=new int[0].ToList();
```

Compared to:

```
var l=new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();
```

You can even initialise the list with values like:

```
var l=new []{1,2,3,4}.ToList();
```

Comment: You can remove the 0 in your declaration.

Comment: `new int[0]{1,2,3,4}` is a syntax error. perhaps `new[]{1,2,3,4}` instead ?

Comment: @CaiusJard Probably a typo, removed it.

Comment: ` int` can be removed too for some more golfy goodness if it can infer the type from the init'r

Comment: @CaiusJard Good point, I think I've even done that a few times as well

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return multiple values from a function, use C# 7 style tuples instead of out parameters:

```
(int,int)d(int a,int b)=>(a/b,a%b);
```

Comment: Oh, didn't knew this was possible in C#. Thanks for sharing, +1 from me! One thing to golf in your code is by using currying input, though (`a=>b=>` instead of `(a,b)=>`). [Here is your code in action](https://tio.run/##hYy9CsIwFEb3PMVdhHuh1j861WYRnBQEB@ebmJZAm0ASBZE@e7S4CA4O3zccDkfHufbBZN1zjHAKvgs8PAVATJyshru3VziydUgTBTg/YjJDub85vbUuFb8Ap3@PpIQWmsyNVI1EXqiCZ4ryVKnFd2znXfS9KS/BJnOwzmCLqyXhhqj@560rwurjjWLMLw), which might be useful to add as example-link to your tip. Oh, and welcome to PPCG! :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen [posted here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85053/15214) :)

Answer (score 3):

Here are my 5 cents:

You can plain replace Math.Max and Math.Min, the following way, to gain 6 bytes:

```
Math.Max(a,b); // turns into:
a>b?a:b;       // saving 6 bytes
```

Another hint is a small way to use a loop, when you are given a variable with "n" times that won't be used anymore (as it will flatten your variable);

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) // turns into: 
while (n-->0)         // saving 8 bytes
```

Method string.Split(' ') has default value whitespace, so if input string has the usual ' ' separation, instead of:

```
string.Split(' ');
```

Write:

```
string.Split() // gain 3 bytes
```

Comment: Some of these become easier with newer .net versions. I should've probably known ahead of time to lock it in at a specific version. These are good optimizations.

Comment: Not locking it allows the answers to improve and keep alive and updated.

Comment: For nitpicking: “has default value space” actually should be “has default value whitespace”. So without `' '` the string will be split also on tab, newline and a few more characters. (“If the separator parameter is `null` or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters. White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard and return `true` if they are passed to the [Char.IsWhiteSpace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace) method.” —    [String.Split Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split))

Answer (score 3):

**Infinite Loops**

Default infinite loop provided in code golf is usually a **while** loop:

```
while(true){...}
```

This can be reduced (-1, as stated earlier) using an inequality:

```
while(1>0){...}
```

But it can be better reduced (-4) using a parameterless **for** command:

```
for(;;){...}
```

Comment: Hey there, welcome to the code golf stack exchange! Great first answer!

Comment: This seems identical to the C answer

Comment: There's also `l:`...`goto l;` Which is same length as a parameterless for when you can't remove the for's brackets

Answer (score 2):

## Implicitly typed arrays

If you need an array (or IEnumerable) initialized with constant data, the most naive implementation might be like so:

```
new int[6]{23,16,278,0,2,44}
```

It's well known that arrays in C# can have implicit length:

```
new int[]{23,16,278,0,2,44}
```

However, for certain data types C# will also be able to determine the base type for the array from its values, making the same declaration even shorter:

```
new[]{23,16,278,0,2,44}
```

[Here](https://tio.run/##xY6xCsIwFEXn5CsenRKMRWupgji56lTBQTqEGDVQE0lCpZR@e0x1tHunB@8eDke4uTBWBlFz5@DVYee5VwIao65w5EoT2gWktL9UwK3l7Raj74UdaPmGYSmqLluxZcGy9YYtWMbyvI/YLXq5eJCGW1BePiP7U1CMUNm6@Er3RjtTy/RsI0EGKj2Z0lul74TCDBJIaFSN0QelJYkj/g8a7ZkoaNqY0OM@fAA) is an example demonstrating that all these options create the same array.

Additionally, specifically if you are creating an array for inline declaration, the `new[]` can be removed as long as the declared variable is not implicitly typed, which can save some bytes:

```
var a=new[]{"woah"};
string[]b={"woah"};
```

Comment: That last line is worth all the weight. Excellent tips!

Answer (score 2):

## Convert a `string` to an `IEnumerable<char>`

Common way would be to use `.ToCharArray()` (14 bytes) or even better `.ToList()` (11 bytes), but the best I found is to rely on `.Skip(0)` (8 bytes).

Most of the time you wont need anything and the string will be cast directly, but sometimes it matters:

```
string.Join("a","bb") // bb
```

vs

```
string.Join("a","bb".Skip(0)) // bab
```

Comment: wait `ToSkip` is a thing?

Comment: @ASCII-only `Skip` ;)

Comment: Then it's no longer 10 bytes

Comment: @ASCII-only yup. 8 bytes \o/

Answer (score 2):

## Tuple Deconstruction

It is possible to deconstruct a `Tuple` into variables using the following syntax:

```
var myTuple = (1, "red", new DateTime(2000, 1, 1));
var (i, c, d) = myTuple;
```

In a code-golf scenario, you could use this to pass a tuple into a function:

```cs
t=>{var(i,c,d)=t;Print(i);Print(c);Print(d);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O@YXJKZn2ejkZlXolNcUpSZl67jkliSGpKZm6ppp5CoYPu/xNauuiyxSCNTJ1knRdO2xDoAqKpEI1MTykiGMVI0rWv/W3MlamgY6igVpaYo6SjkpZYrwIzTMDIwMNBRMAQiTU1N6/8A)

A more practical use of this is to decompose a list of tuples and iterate over them using `foreach`.

```cs
var myTuples = new[] {
    (1, "red", new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)),
    (2, "blue", new DateTime(2000, 1, 1))
};
foreach (var (i, c, d) in myTuples) {
    Print(i);
    Print(c);
    Print(d);
}
```

Or in a code-golf scenario:

```cs
t=>{foreach(var(i,c,d)in t){Print(i);Print(c);Print(d);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY0xC8IwEIX3/oqjUw5OaLumLQgugoODmzjENOqBppCcOpT@9hiRbsIbPh7f49m4spHT2gqPvt3uOEqr2AtFCeyvtDHiDvxw2PdgoEvS9dNlDM7Ym3qZoJgsDcgeBKd9Xohi1D@wCwyo5znpwijv3sfTVAComsrghpIgV7CcqKaqKoI6B5G@WkPl@f50/70mB7GYUacP)

Answer (score 2):

Use Range instead of Substring:

```cs
var s="abcdef";
Console.Write(s.Substring(2,2)); // "cd"
Console.Write(s[2..4]); // "cd"
```

[It doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61882077) if type is not known at compile time:

```cs
dynamic s="abcdef";
Console.Write(s[2..4]); // runtime error
Console.Write($"{s}"[2..4]); // "cd"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary operator to shorten complex `if..else` constructs even if you need to work on multiple or different variables in different branches.
You can sometimes save some chars by doing all or part of the work in the 3rd part of a `for`.
...and also other "optimizations", you can find in this example, I submitted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/38116/18285) (it increments all numbers in a string given as char array or StringBuilder):

```c#
for (int b=3, c, i=a.Length; i-->0;
    b=48>c|c>57
        ?7
        :b>2
            ?c>56?a[i]='0':++a[i]*0
            :b
) c=a[i];
```

In two of the branches, `b` isn't really set; in two branches, `a[i]` is set even though it says `b=` in the beginning; in one case `a[i]` and `b` are set simultaneously...

`c>56` is shorter than `c==57`

`i=a.Length; i-->0;` is a lot shorter than `i=a.Length-1; i>=0; i--`

Answer (score 1):

One thing I just learned (which I didn't know but probably all of you do): You do not need a namespace at all. If it is a simple program which doesn't use many namespaces that you would need to shorten, just omit the `namespace` and start with `class Foo{...`.

Any objections to this or hints why I shouldn't do this are very welcome, as I'm just writing up my first "golfed" (as far as I got) answer in C# ;-)

Comment: Alternately by putting the namespace as system you can omit the common `using System;` declaration ...

Answer (score 1):

Convert line endings from CRLF to LF before counting bytes ☺

Comment: This really applies to all languages, and preprocessor directives are pretty rare in C# golf, so few programs will ever need to be on more than one line.

Comment: Mh but it's still non-obvious to some people. And most other languages are more often seen on `LF`-only environments. I don't expect it to help much, but… why not?

Comment: Most of the time, just remove newlines...

Answer (score 1):

### ReSharper tips

If you have used ReSharper to get to the initial working solution before golfing, note that it often generates

- `readonly` variables
- `static` methods, if they do not use any fields

If you have R#, you want to use the *inline method* refactoring for methods that are only called once, since they only need the additional method declaration.

Comment: Or Rider, which is currently in free beta (unlike R#).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that C# uses unicode (which includes ascii). All `char` are `int` under the hood.

For example `'a'` is `97`.

- `n=>char.IsDigit(n)|char.IsUpper(n)`
- `n=>n>47&n<58|n>64&n<91` // note that I use a bitwise comparator [see](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84903/15214)

example: [Code golf to make logos for New Stack exchange sites](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84898/15214)

---

Since `char` are `int`, you can increment them:

- `for(int x=31;x<126;)Console.Write((char)++x);`
- `for(char x=' ';x<127;)Console.Write(x++);`

example: [Print the ASCII printable character set](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85126/15214)

Use the [unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character) for reference. Be careful one byte != one character.

Comment: `int`s are 4 bytes, but `char`s are only 2.

Answer (score 1):

## Using Command-Line Options

[Command-line options are not included in the byte count of your program](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/84206), so they are very useful. However, keep in mind that when you use a command-line option, you are not competing in C# anymore, you are competing in C# with `-yourflag`.

The syntax for them is to put a `-` or a `/` preceding the letter, and if there are any arguments, you use `:` to separate the option name from the argument.

There are 3 command-line options that I know of as of right now:

- `/u` or `-u` or `/using` or `-using`

  - Acts as a `using` statement. Example: `/u:System.Text.RegularExpressions`. You can do static imports with them by just adding the class name, like `/u:System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`. For example, if you have `/u:System.String` as an option, you can just use `Concat(yourString)` instead of `string.Concat(yourString)`. Sadly, aliasing doesn't seem to work. You can also put multiple imports on the same line with `;` as a delimiter like this: `/u:System.Math;System.CodeDom`.
- `/i` or `-i`, activates REPL mode. Code from the input box is also evaluated and printed.

  - Can be useful for situations where hard-coding is allowed, e.g. if input `insertRandomTermHere` output 3, if input `anotherRandomTerm` output 4, we can just do `int insertRandomTermHere=3,anotherRandomTerm=4;`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/M69EITOvOLWoxD01L7UoMzkktSjXI7Uo1dZYJzEvvyQjtSgoMS8lPxckbmtiDdKBRTUXhtp/@QUlmfl5xf91MwE)
- `/r` or `-r`

  - Acts as an assembly reference. Allows you to use types like those in `System.Numerics` or `System.Drawing`. If you want to use `BigInteger`, an assembly reference is required.

Meanwhile, happy [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)ing!

Comment: Where did you find these flags in the docs? I can only find something about [the default Roslyn flags](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/compilers/CSharp/CommandLine.md).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Experimentation :)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/5857

Comment: "*Command-line options are not included in the byte count of your program*" [citation needed]

Comment: @PeterTaylor Added relevant link to meta

Answer (score 1):

## Use `dynamic` instead of types with longer names in function declarations

For example, instead of
`DateTime f(int y)=>`…
use
`dynamic f(int y)=>`…

Comment: Why wouldn't I just use var here?

Comment: @jcolebrand Clarified.

Answer (score 1):

The first and third sections of `for` can contain multiple comma-separated *statement expressions*, including assignments (but not declarations) and method calls:

```cs
for(i=0,k=1;i<n;Console.WriteLine(k),k*=3)i++;
```