# Circular shift an arbitrary byte-array bitwise

Tags: code-golf

Given an arbitrary array of octets, and an offset measured in bits, the goal is to bitwise left rotate the array by the specified number of bit positions as if the entire array were a single contiguous number. Byte order is big-endian.

As an example, given the (not zero terminated) ASCII string `abcd` and a shift of 5 bits. we turn this array of bytes:

```
01100001 01100010 01100011 01100100
```

into this one:

```
00101100 01001100 01101100 10001100
```

Notice that the bits propagate to the left from byte to byte and that they wrap back around.

Now that I think you've all got the idea, the rules:

- Your program should accept an arbitrary unsigned integer (**"number of bits to shift" non-negative, possibly zero, limited only by the size of the standard integer type**) and a raw stream of octets of arbitrary length (**you may assume the length is strictly positive**). How you accept these is up to you (**file,stdin,parameter are all acceptable**). Your program should output the shifted bytes in an analogous manner (**i.e. file,stdout,return value**).
- "Cut-and-paste" style code is **not allowed**. That is, you can't rely on your user to set the value of a certain variable before calling your code.
- The byte ordering is **big-endian**.
- Shortest code wins.

**EDIT: It's clear now I should have restricted the input output format a bit more. The solutions that are using ASCII 0s and 1s directly aren't very interesting unfortunately.**

Comment: What's the range of valid input? Can the shift be negative? Zero? Greater than or equal to the number of bits in the array? Can the array be of length zero?

Comment: One of those questions is already answered, but I will clarify.

Comment: @PeterTaylor better?

Comment: Does it need to be a complete program?

Comment: I just want to ask why byte order matters?

Comment: @tia um... I am not certain it does. At the time I wrote it, it seemed like it did, but now I can't tell why. This idea came from something I was working on today, so it probably crept in from there.

Comment: @tia: Byte order matters for storing extended-precision integers in memory.  For example, an extended-precision library like http://gmplib.org/ stores the "limbs" in native-endian, so you can use word-sized shifts for shift-counts that aren't a multiple of 8 (in which case it's a memcpy with an offset).  To get the behaviour shown for the `abcd` char-array example, on a little-endian machine you can't load the whole thing as a 32-bit integer and rotate left by 5.  If you did that, bits coming out the top of `a` would go into `b` rather than wrapping around to `d`.

Comment: A C answer that treated the input as an `int[]` would work on big-endian implementations (and working on at least one implementation is enough for code-golf), but an x86 asm or machine-code answer would have to use byte shifts.

Comment: Has this ever been re-asked in a way that stops answers from doing input/output with each "bit" in a separate byte?  Totally agree that defeats the purpose of the question, since it just turns it into a memory-addressing problem.

Comment: Can we have some sample inputs/outputs? Like, (5, "abcd") should become...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## APL (1)

it's a builtin

```
      5⌽0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

### C 89

Shifting is done in-place in `*s` array. `l` is array length and `f` is number of bits to shift.

```
void f(char*s,l,f){while(f--)for(int i=0,j,c=*s<0;s[j=i++]<<=1,s[j]+=i%l?s[i]<0:c,i<l;);}
```

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <s>321</s> <s>308</s> 304 bytes

```cs
var y=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(args[1]).ToList();int i=int.Parse(args[0]),m,j=0;for(;i>7;y.RemoveAt(0),i-=8)y.Add(y[0]);byte c=0,u;for(m=8-i;j<y.Count;j++){u=(byte)((255<<m&y[j])>>m);if(j<1)c=u;y[j]<<=i;if(j>0)y[j-1]|=u;}y[^1]|=c;Console.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(y.ToArray()));
```

Dropped 13 bytes thanks to awesome suggestions from **Kevin**, and  another 4 bytes with suggestions from **ceilingcat**!

Uncompressed version below. This uses C# v9 [top-level statements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements) feature, so the program below compiles into an executable. Program expects two arguments: bits and bytes in a form of a UTF8 string (e.g., execute is as `./program 5 abcd`).

```csharp
// get bytes from the provided provided (assumed in UTF8)
var y = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(args[1]).ToList();
int i = int.Parse(args[0]), m, j = 0; // i - how many bits to shift

// rotate full bytes first if bits >= 8
for (; i > 7; y.RemoveAt(0), i -= 8) // drop the first byte
    y.Add(y[0]); // append first byte to the end

byte c = 0, u; // c keeps the bits to wrap around from first byte to the last
               // u will be used to shift bits between neighboring bytes

// now i < 8 guaranteed
for (m = 8 - i; j < y.Count; j++)
{
    u = (byte) ((255 << m & y[j]) >> m); // bits to shift
    if (j < 1) c = u; // if we are on the first byte, store them in c
    y[j] <<= i; // shift the byte
    if (j > 0) y[j - 1] |= u; // shift the cutoff bits to prev byte
                              // if current byte is not the first byte
}

y[^1] |= c; // wrap around the bits

// and output
Console.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(y.ToArray()));
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in C#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c) page for ways you can golf your program! You might want to add a [TIO](https://tio.run/#cs-code) link or similar so others can test your code online.

Comment: @emanresuA Thanks! TIO's C# does not seem to support C#'s top-level statements and I couldn't find an online C# compiler that supports command line arguments...

Comment: `while(i>7){y.Add(y[0]);y.RemoveAt(0);i-=8;}` can be `for(;i>7;y.RemoveAt(0),i-=8)y.Add(y[0]);` for -3 and `var i=int.Parse(args[0])` + `var m=8-i;byte c=0,u;for(var j=0;` can be `int i=int.Parse(args[0]),m,j=0;byte c=0,u;for(m=8-1;` for another -6. And if there isn't an online compiled for C# 9+, you could put the `args` in the header on TIO (and replace `^1` with `y.Count-1`, since TIO is below C# v8 apparently): [try it online](https://tinyurl.com/2p92sxks). Oh, and welcome to CGCC. :)

Comment: You can also golf the `WriteLine` to `Write` for another -4. (And apparently the Visual C# Online Compiler uses `Args` for the same behavior as `args`, so you could actually save an additional byte by using Visual C# Interactive Compiler as language and sacrificing `^1` to `y.Count-1` to remove `Console.` for -1: [try it online](https://tinyurl.com/3rvxprx9). But if you prefer to use standard `C#` with `^1` and top-level arguments I can understand.)

Comment: Thanks @ceilingcat for some great suggestions! Another 4 bytes off!

Comment: Thanks @KevinCruijssen ! 13 bytes are gone :) I am just starting golfing in C# (and in general) so all the advice is helping me a lot! I prefer to use standard C# :)

Answer (score 2):

### Sed, 35 bytes

```
:a
s/1-\(.\)\(.*\)/-\2\1/
ta
s/.//
```

Takes input on stdin, as number of bits to shift by in unary, followed by `-`, followed by the binary stream, without spaces. e.g.

```
echo 11111-01100001011000100110001101100100 | sed -f a.sed
```

outputs

```
00101100010011000110110010001100
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 33 (32 + 1 for `-p`)

```
1while(s/1-(.)(.*)/-$2$1/);s/.//
```

Takes input on stdin, as number of bits to shift by in unary, followed by -, followed by the binary stream, without spaces. e.g.

```
echo 11111-01100001011000100110001101100100 | perl -pe '1while(s/1-(.)(.*)/-$2$1/);s/.//'
```

Comment: I can't find any rule you are breaking, although this isn't what I intended, since I didn't specify an encoding. Clever idea.

Comment: @Tim: I sort of took off from `How you accept these is up to you`, since the input was mostly unspecified. As an aside, this can take arbitrarily large shifts and bits. Also, taking the count in decimal would have made the sed version much longer.

Answer (score 1):

### APL (23)

```
{2⊥⍉(8,⍨⍴⍵)⍴⍺⌽,⍉⍵⊤⍨8/2}
```

This is a function that takes the rotation as its left argument and the byte array as its right argument (as numbers).

```
      5{2⊥⍉(8,⍨⍴⍵)⍴⍺⌽,⍉⍵⊤⍨8/2}97 98 99 100
44 76 108 140
```

Answer (score 1):

**C# (210)**

```
void r(byte[] a, int n){string s="";for(int i=0;i<a.Length;i++)s+=Convert.ToString(a[i],2).PadLeft(8,'0');s=s.Substring(n)+s.Substring(0,n);for(int i=0;i<a.Length;i++)a[i]=Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i*8,8),2);}
```

This is a function 'r' in C# that takes a byte[] and an integer n.
It does in-place rotation, so the original array is rotated, and nothing is returned.

I convert the byte array to string of bits, rotate, and convert back to bytes.
It seems like a cheat, but the requirements does not prevent it.

The pretty code is following:

```
void r(byte[] a, int n)
{
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        s += Convert.ToString(a[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0');

    s = s.Substring(n) + s.Substring(0, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        a[i] = Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i * 8, 8), 2);
}
```

Comment: As long as it works, you can do it however you want. Efficiency isn't required in code-golf.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 142 bytes

It's huge :(

Input is taken from parameters, `puts` shifted string to stdout.

```
main(int d,char**v){d=strtoul(v[1],0,10);while(d--){v[1]=v[2]+1;**v=*v[2];strcpy(v[2],v[1]);while(*(v[1]++));*v[1]--=0;*v[1]=**v;}puts(v[2]);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## q (18)

depending on how picky you are about exact output format and launch, i can get it down to 18 in q:

```
$ ls -l shift*.q
-rw-r--r-- 1 daviaaro ccM504 19 Jan  8 16:05 shift1.q
-rw-r--r-- 1 daviaaro ccM504 22 Jan  8 16:07 shift2.q
-rw-r--r-- 1 daviaaro ccM504 25 Jan  8 16:07 shift3.q
$ cat shift1.q
(rotate)."I*"$.z.x
$ q shift1.q 5 "01100001011000100110001101100100" <&-
"00101100010011000110110010001100"
$ cat shift2.q
-1(rotate)."I*"$.z.x;
$ q shift2.q 5 01100001011000100110001101100100 <&-
00101100010011000110110010001100
$ cat shift3.q
-1(rotate)."I*"$.z.x;
\\
$ q shift3.q -q 5 01100001011000100110001101100100
00101100010011000110110010001100
$
```

of course, it helps that the actual function happens to be in the standard lib :)

all three interpret two command-line args as int and string and rotate the string by the int

the first case just shows the string representation of the string (a (mostly) pasteable notation)

the second and third cases print it

in the first two cases, i'm relying on q to quit itself when run without stdin

the third case has an explicit quit command (and an extra command-line arg to suppress the REPL welcome message, which is automatically suppressed in the other cases due to stdin being closed)

note btw that the byte counts from ls include newlines, even on the two one-line files, and since q is fine with code files that are missing their last newline, the actual counts are 18, 21, and 24

ETA:

how do you feel about this?

```
$ q<<<'5 rotate 01100001011000100110001101100100b'
00101100010011000110110010001100b
$
```

is it valid? how would you count it? (the `b` is q's notation for a binary vector/bitstring. if you prefer, it would also work on the string version at the cost of an extra character)

Comment: The first one seems to break the requirement "Your program should output the shifted bytes in an analogous manner" in my opinion, since you accept input without quotes and return it with quotes. The second one seems to require the `<&-` on the commandline; that would have to be included in the character count.

Comment: And the `-q` flag counts as one extra character, so your counts from my point of view are: 21(but not valid), 24, and 25. Feel free to argue your case. Either of the second two answers are acceptable.

Comment: well, it sort of depends on the details. without the `<&-`, version two will still work, but the REPL will print a welcome banner and will remain open for interactive use after the program finishes. without the `-q`, version 3 will exit, but it will still print the welcome banner. if it matters, the welcome banner is printed to stderr, while the output is printed to stdout. would you consider any of those situations acceptable answers?

Comment: i'd like to note that the APL solution above doesn't seem to be getting charged for a newline . if we want to talk about solutions valid interactively rather than as code files, i have a full solution in six characters: `rotate`. :-p

Comment: Printing the banner to standard error is fine I guess. Keeping the REPL open is not. If I am keeping track then properly that means the last two solutions are both 24 then.

Comment: Regarding my first solution, note that it’s perfectly fine to invoke it with quotes around the bitstring—it has no particular effect on anything, since the shell will remove them, but it will make the input and output formats match. Does that change your stance on that one? Counting the `<&-`, it’s 21 characters.

Comment: Yeah. I thought of that already, I already decided to allow that as long as you suggested the idea.

Comment: ok, edited to reflect

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <strike>43</strike> 42 bytes

Takes shifts and data from stdin, returns shifted data in stdout.
Input format is `<shift_amount>\n<data>`

```
a=-input();b=raw_input();print b[a:]+b[:a]
```

Comment: Can you please describe the input format, since I don't know the exact semantics of `input` and `raw_input`? I haven't used python in a while.

Comment: @Tim `raw_input()` fetches an input line from stdin (`sys.stdin.readline()`) and removes `\n`. `input()` does the same but `eval()`s input before returning. Input format is thus `<shift_amount>\n<data>`.

Comment: You've shifted *byte*wise.  Not bitwise.  Huge difference here.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 40 Bytes

```
s,n=open(0);print(n[int(s):]+n[:int(s)])
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1gnzza/IDVPw0DTuqAoM69EIy8aRBZrWsVq50VbQdixmv//m3IZGBoaAIEhhAZiCA3hAxEA)

This is basically a port of Oberons answer, and takes the same input from stdin as his Python 2 solution:

```
in:
5
01100001011000100110001101100100
out:
00101100010011000110110010001100
```

this is also my first post on this site, happy to be here!

Comment: Welcome to the site.