# Implement t9-like functionality

Tags: code-golf, number, function

Your challenge today is to implement a [t9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T9_(predictive_text))-like functionality.

You will implement a function that will only have 2 parameters.
You will receive 1 phone number in a string and the content of a text file with a list of words (don't assume a specific newline style).
You can use the link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eneko/data-repository/master/data/words.txt to test the functionality, or use `/usr/share/dict/words` (check [A text file with a list of words [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741003/a-text-file-with-a-list-of-words) for more information).

You can assume that you will always receive at least 2 numbers.

Given the number, you will read from a list of words and returns the words starting with the letters mapping to those words. This means that the input should be only numbers from 2 to 9.
You can do whatever you want if you receive invalid input.

If no match is found, you can return an empty list, `null`/`nil` or `0`.

Remember that the cellphone keys are mapped to their equivalent chars:

- 0 and 1 are invalid
- 2 matches [abc]
- 3 matched [def]
- 4 matches [ghi]
- 5 matches [jkl]
- 6 matches [mno]
- 7 matches [pqrs]
- 8 matches [tuv]
- and 9 matches [wxyz]

Examples:

```
f('52726')
//returns ["Japan","japan","Japanee","Japanese","Japanesque"...,"larbowlines"]

f('552')
//returns ["Kjeldahl","kjeldahlization","kjeldahlize"...,"Lleu","Llew"]

f('1234')
//makes demons fly out your nose or divide by 0

f('9999')
//returns ["Zyzzogeton"]

f('999999')
//returns [] or null/nil or 0
```

After you run your function, you can print it in any way you wish.

Rules:

- Standard loopholes are INVALID
- You must return something, even if it is `null`/`nil`
  Javascript will return `undefined` if you don't return something, therefore this rule.
- You cannot use or re-implement other's answers or copy my implementation.
- You can assume, for Javascript, that the browser will be already opened and that the `innerText`/`textContent` of the automatic element will be passed as the 2nd parameter
- For compiled languages, you cannot pass special arguments to the compiler
- You can receive the file name over compiler arguments
- Variables, macros, global variables, constants, non-standard classes and all the sort passing other values inside the function will be considered invalid.
- In Javascript, variables without the keyword `var` render your code invalid
- Your function will be named `f`
- You can only and only have 2 arguments on your function
- Try to keep your code under 500 seconds to run.
- You don't have to worry about whitespace
- You must use only [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) printable characters.
  Exceptions are languages that **only** use non-printable characters (APL and whitespace are 2 examples).

Scoring:

- **Lowest number of bytes win**
- Having invalid [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) printable characters in your answer, will count as the answer being encoded in [UTF-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32)
  The exception to the encoding will make your answer be count by **characters**.
- Only the function body counts, don't count anything else you do outside it
- Bonus of -30% if you make a prediction system based on the neighborhood or most common words
- Bonus of -20% in size if you only return the first 5 matches for each letter corresponding to the first number (e.g.: 245 would returns 5 words starting with 'a', 5 starting with 'b' and 5 starting with 'c').

Here is an example of an implementation, using Javascript:

```
function f(phone, words)
{
    var keypad=['','','abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqrs','tuv','wxyz'];
    var regex='';

    for(var i=0,l=phone.length;i<l;i++)
    {
        regex+='['+keypad[phone[i]]+']';
    }

    var regexp=new RegExp('\\s('+regex+'[a-z]*)\\s','gi');

    return words.match(regexp);
}
```

To run it, open the list link and run, for example:

```
f('9999',document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerText);
//returns [" Zyzzogeton "]
```

This example was tested and works under Opera 12.17 64bits on Windows 7 Home Edition 64bits.

Comment: Is the second argument to the program a file name containing the words or the list of words itself ?

Comment: @MartinBüttner UTF-8 isn't unfair (it still counts ASCII chars as being 1 byte), but I changed the rule.

Comment: @Optimizer The 2nd argument is a list of the words. You can pass the filename over a compiler argument and read the file, if you want to. But the only thing that counts is the function body.

Comment: @MartinBüttner By counting as ASCII, it is being counted as bytes. You want me to say that APL code will have 1 byte having the size of 8 bits?

Comment: @MartinBüttner I think it is more fair now. The required encoding is specified (printable ASCII characters) but APL answers will be count by characters.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Now it is more fair: All languages that only use non-printable ascii chars are counted by chars. All the others are counted by bytes.

Comment: Can you explain your first bonus a bit more please ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure space, tab and newline (which are the only characters Whitespace uses) are printable. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but by "You don't have to worry about whitespace" I assume you mean whitespace doesn't count. In that case, a Whitespace answer would instantly win with a score of 0.

Comment: @Optimizer The t9 function tries to predict the most used words. You can use this to, for example, list the most commonly used words in english. An example would be to only return `["Japan", "japan", "Japanese"]` with the example number "52726".

Comment: @nyuszika7h The whitespace being returned don't count. you can return `["a"]` or `[" a "]`. And you made a nice point about whitespace. In this case, what I am referring to is characters that show when you print. A space won't be printed, unless you put a background from a different color than the paper (some printers optimize its printing based on the paper color), but you don't have to go on this extend.

Comment: -1 for inappropriate restrictions

Comment: @AJMansfield "-1 for inappropriate restrictions" --> please, develop more about this. This type of comment is as useful as going to a concert with an air guitar.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Specifically, rules 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 are all inappropriate. Additionally, rules 4, 12, S2, and S3 are also poor.

Comment: @AJMansfield rule `2`: if it doesn't return something, it isn't a function. `3`: you want to copy people's answers? `5`: the goal is to create a function, not a full-blown program. `6`: that is to enforce the scoring, to avoid cheaters. `7`: refer to rule 6. `8`: this is to avoid multiple function names. `9`: check the implementations: you only need 2 arguments. 'poor rules': `4`: indeed the wording is poor, but check my javascript implementation for the reason why. `12`: indeed it is badly worded. `s2`: refer to rule 13. `s3`: the goal is to make a function, this is **FAIR**

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Which leads to the heart of the issue. Limiting allowed programs to just functions is unreasonable, as that makes a large class of possible solutions 'invalid', such as shell scripts or command-line applications. Those rules get in the way of the fun of making super-optimized programs.

Comment: So 2 is invalid because the goal shouldn't be to make a function. 3 is invalid because it means that I can't post a super-tightly optimized version of another solution. 5 is simply wrong. 6 is already covered by standard loopholes, and your version of it is bad. Same for 7, plus the 'function' thing. 8 is overly restrictive. 9 but that may preclude certain types of optimization, such as multi-argument recursion. 4 is just an excuse to let you shorten your code. You should just use one of the regular scoring rules; S2 is worse than any of them. S3 is bad because of the function thing.

Comment: @AJMansfield 2 is perfectly fine. Look up at the tags. 3 is perfectly fine too. The goal is exactly that. If you want to answer, make your own answer. 5 is fine: no need for compiler arguments when all you have to do is a function. Without the rule 8, I would have to count the whole code and making a function wouldn't make any sense. 9: if you want recursion, use `eval` or lambda functions. 4 is not an excuse but a facility. If you post an answer in javascript, you can count that the page will already be opened on the file. s3 is perfect. you can make shorter functions with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## CJam, 28 bytes

```
q~{el{'h-_9/-D+3/}%s1$#!},p;
```

Takes input in the form of `"<number>" [<list of words>]`

Example:

```
"52726" ["Japan" "japan" "Japanee" "Japanese" "Japanesque" "larbowlines" "ablution" "ablutionary" "abluvion" "ably" "abmho" "Abnaki" "abnegate"]
```

Output:

```
["Japan" "japan" "Japanee" "Japanese" "Japanesque" "larbowlines"]
```

Not going for any bonus for now.

[Try the code online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/) but for actual time measurements, run it on the [Java compiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/)

*Note that CJam represents empty lists like `""`*

To convert the raw wordlist into CJam list use the following code with the wordlist as input:

```
qN/p
```

Comment: "You will receive 1 phone number in a string and the content of a text file with a list of words" -> can you implement, on a different block, the needed code to read the file into an usable list?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel You mean not the part of this code, but just a helper code to convert the list to correct format ?

Comment: Exactly. Which your code isn't enough to prove it can use a list of words as the provided examples. But I upvoted anyway, I just wanted that helper code.

Comment: Can you add it to the answer? As an edit, in a different part

Comment: Exactly. That's what I'm talking about! Lets see if you can optimize it even further

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel note that the online compiler is not the official one and is at least 10 times slower than the official command line Java compiler.

Comment: Don't worry, timing isn't critical. As stated on the rules: "**Try** to keep your code under 500 seconds to run". Nobody wants to wait 300 years for a word list while writing an important SMS for your boss.

Comment: If you want to go for the 20% bonus, check my answer. You have an example of how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

## Java: 395

This forms a regex pattern based on the letters that are allowed for each number, and then tacks on a .* at the end to match any following characters.

Here is the golfed version:

```
static ArrayList<String> f(String n,ArrayList<String> d){String[] k={"","","([A-Ca-c])","([D-Fd-f])","([G-Ig-i])","([J-Lj-l])","([M-Om-o])","([P-Sp-s])","([T-Vt-v])","([W-Zw-z])"};String r="";for(int i=0;i<n.length();++i)r+=k[n.charAt(i)-'0'];r += ".*";Pattern p=Pattern.compile(r);ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();for(String w:dictionary)if(p.matcher(w).matches())a.add(w);return a;}
```

And here is the ungolfed version for read-ability

```
public static ArrayList<String> f(String phoneNumber, ArrayList<String> dictionary) {

    String[] KEY_VALUES = {"", "", "([A-Ca-c])", "([D-Fd-f])", "([G-Ig-i])",
                                            "([J-Lj-l])", "([M-Om-o])", "([P-Sp-s])",
                                            "([T-Vt-v])", "([W-Zw-z])"};

    String regex = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length(); ++i) {
        regex += KEY_VALUES[phoneNumber.charAt(i) - '0'];
    }
    regex += ".*";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String word : dictionary) {
        if (p.matcher(word).matches()) {
            answers.add(word);
        }
    }
    return answers;
}
```

Comment: Your code goes against rule number 7: "Variables, macros, global variables, constants, non-standard classes and all the sort passing other values inside the function will be considered invalid." and it kinda goes against rule number 3: "You cannot use or re-implement other's answers or copy my implementation.", but on your code it is kinda debatable. And it also goes against the rule 9: "Your function will be named `f`".

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Oops.  Rule 7 can be easily fixed by moving the constant inside the function.  I was just pulling it outside the function for better programming style.  Rule 9 is also an easy fix.  I confess I didn't read your answer, so I didn't intentionally try to copy it.  I can remove my answer if you think it is too close for the contest.

Comment: Your answer is alright. You have a bug on your code. On the last constant (`([W-Zw-z)]`) it should be `([W-Zw-z])`. And on Code-golf you don't have to worry about programming styles and good practices: your code must simply do it's thing withing the required parameters. If you check my answer, you will see this line: `$s=[2=>abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqrs,tuv,wxyz];`. This is an awful 'crime' in PHP. Basically I am forcing PHP to convert non-existing constants into strings. This is perfectly acceptable. You will also see that I'm not even setting the variable `$t` to an array before using it as such

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Good catch on the regex error.  Thanks for pointing it out.  I'll try to actually golf it tomorrow; maybe find some Java examples on this site.

Comment: I'm not a java programmer, but I tell you some things. You can check http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java to get some tips. General tips include removing useless whitespace (newlines, spaces, tabs), one-letter-long variable names and do all that you can to reduce the code size as much as possible.

Comment: Nice!!! I don't know if it is possible, but maybe you can store (inside the function) a reference to `ArrayList` and `Pattern`? (I don't know if this is possible: I'm not a Java programmer) But really nice looking code! You really golfed the heck out of it!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel when you say store a reference to, do you mean as a way to shorten the names?

Comment: Exactly, as long as it is inside the body. You have a few repeated data types (I think I can call them that) that you can try to shorten.

Answer (score 1):

## C# .NET 4.5 235

This should work:

```
IEnumerable<string>F(string n,string d){IEnumerable<string>w=d.Split(null).ToList();string[]a={"","","abc","def","ghi", "jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"};foreach(var i in n){w=w.Where(x=>x.IndexOfAny(a[i-'0'].ToArray())>0);}return w;}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Your code will work, but you still need to reduce it a lot more. By removing all useless whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines) I have managed to reduce your code to 167 bytes. This code can be reduced a lot more, I'm sure of it. I recommend reading http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c to shorten even more your code. To help you a little, the word list is a string separated by newlines, and you seem to assume it is already possible to use a `foreach` in it. If you expect it to already be `IEnumerable`, include the code used outside

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel TY I will look at it. List are a IEnumerable there is no code outside what I posted.

Comment: If you look at the specification of the function, you will see the 2nd parameter is also a string. (Quoting: "You will receive 1 phone number in a string and the content of a text file with a list of words (don't assume a specific newline style).") And you have 1 useless whitespace on your `a` var.

Comment: I've noticed the improvements on your question, and I gave you an upvote. But you still can save a byte on your `a` var. But I really see noticeable improvements! Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 (155 bytes)

Should also work in Python 3 with the appropriate replacements (`string`->`bytes`, `b` prefix on strings, etc.).

I wasn't sure if having the `maketrans` call outside the function is considered "fair"; if not, the function is 134 bytes with it moved inside.

**EDIT:** Dropped one byte from a stupid oversight.

With prepared `maketrans`, 67 bytes:

```py
from string import maketrans
t=maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','22233344455566677778889999')

def f(n,w):
    return[x for x in w.split()if x.lower().translate(t).startswith(n)]
```

With `maketrans` in body, 134 bytes:

```py
from string import maketrans

def f(n,w):
    return[x for x in w.split()if x.lower().translate(maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','22233344455566677778889999')).startswith(n)]
```

With `import` and `maketrans` in body, 155 bytes:

```py
def f(n,w):
    return[x for x in w.split()if x.lower().translate(__import__('string').maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','22233344455566677778889999')).startswith(n)]
```

Test call:

```py
print f('9999',open('words.txt','rt').read())
```

Comment: The `maketrans` is part of the function body. You should move it. I don't know if it is even possible, but you can try to directly use the `import`. I think I saw it somewhere... But your code is really nice!

Comment: Do you mean to move the import *and* call into the body? Yes, I think that can be done, too.

Comment: I was thinking about `t=(from stirng import maketrans)([...])`. I have no idea if it is even possible. But maybe you can use `from string import as x  t=x([...])` which I'm not sure if it is possible too :/

Comment: The correct version is the last one. But the answer as-is is acceptable in my opinion. +1 for `__import__('string').maketran`.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've removed the invalid answers.

Comment: Those were alright, you could keep them anyway

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 5.4+ (<del>171</del> 186-20% = 148.8 bytes):

Well, this is quite a huge answer, but well.

I hope this brings more people to answer.

This function expects the **raw** content being read.

Here is the code:

```
function f($_,$a){$s=[2=>abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqrs,tuv,wxyz];$a=preg_split('@\r\n|\r|\n@',$a);for($i=0;$c=$_[$i];++$i)foreach($a as$k=>$v)if(!strpos(1..$s[$c],$v[$i])||$t[$v[0]]++>4)unset($a[$k]);return$a;}
```

This works by verifying that the letter is in the list of allowed letters.

Example: the input `36` would make to check if `1abc` has the first letter of the word and that `1def` has the 2nd letter.

I append `1` so it doesn't check if the letter is in the 1st position (which would return `0` and that would evaluate to `false`). `if(!strpos(1..$s[$c],$v[$i]))` or `if(!strpos($c.$s[$c],$v[$i]))` will have the same effect, but the 1st confuses more and I like it.

Failing to do so, will remove the word.

With no words left, it returns an empty array.

To test this online, go to http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and create a simple variable with a word for line.

A testable example:

```
function f($_,$a)
{
    $s=array(2=>abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqrs,tuv,wxyz);
    $a=preg_split('@\r\n|\r|\n@',$a);

    for($i=0;$c=$_[$i];++$i)
        foreach($a as$k=>$v)
            if(!strpos(1..$s[$c],$v[$i]) || $t[$v[0]]++>4)
                unset($a[$k]);
    return$a;
}

$lines=<<<WORDS
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
WORDS;

var_dump(f('36',$lines));
```

This should output:

```
array(1) {
    [3]=>
      string(4) "four"
}
```

To work on older php versions, replace `$s=[2=>abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqrs,tuv,wxyz];` by `$s=array(2=>abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqrs,tuv,wxyz);`

---

For the 20% bonus:

To reduce the code I simply added `||$t[$v[0]]++>4`, which checks how many times the first letter was used.

In php, `$t` doesn't need to be defined, helping to reduce a big chunk of *37.2* bytes.

To see this effect, use the following variable as the 2nd argument:

```
$lines=<<<WORDS
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
twelve
time
tutor
test
truth
WORDS;
```