# Program touch-tone instructions for my fingers

Tags: code-golf

The keypad on my office phone has the following layout:

```
[1]  [2]  [3]
/.@  ABC  DEF

[4]  [5]  [6]
GHI  JKL  MNO

[7]  [8]  [9]
PQRS TUV WXYZ

[*]  [0]  [#]
 +    _
```

#### Task:

Write a program that, given an input string, returns a list of instructions that my fingers need to follow in order the type/dial the message/number.

#### Rules:

- 3 fingers (1,2 & 3) start on keys [4], [5] and [6]. This starting position is 0.
- The only instruction a finger receives is its new relative location.
- Once a key has been pressed, that is the finger's new starting position. Fingers do not return to their 'home row'.
- Moving a finger up the keypad's column is -1, -2 or -3, depending on where it was last used.
- Moving a finger down the keypad's column is 1, 2 or 3, depending on where it was last used.
- Keeping a finger on the same key means there is no movement (0). It is not included.
- Words which require a double letter (like 'OO' in 'BOOK' or 'DE' in CODE) will need a pause (P) between letters.
- When using Pause, the finger is not specified.
- A finger can only press the keys in its own column (1,4,7,*) (2,5,8,0) (3,6,9,#)
- Typing certain letters requires multiple keypresses. To type 'F', 3 needs to be pressed 3 times.
- Input is not case sensitive.
- Input characters not available on the keypad should be ignored. (Hyphens and parenthesis of a phone number, for example)
- Input will either be alpha or numeric - not a mixture - so no need to switch between input methods mid-stream.
- When entering numbers, Pauses aren't necessary.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes wins.

#### Update

To slightly simplify matters, [*] and [#] can be ignored. These will not feature in the input. But I'll buy you a beer if you do include them and get lowest byte count! (If you're in London ;-))

#### Output:

A list of instructions, in the following format:

```
[direction] [finger_number] [new_relative_location], ...
```

Whitespace between instructions is optional.

#### Test cases:

```
(123)-957 -> -11, -21, -31, 32, 21, 12
555-9273 -> 2,2,2,31,-21,11,-32
CODE GOLF -> -21,2,2, 3,3,3, -31, P, 3,3, 23, 1, 31,3,3, -22,2,2, -31,3,3
Code Golf -> -21,2,2, 3,3,3, -31, P, 3,3, 23, 1, 31,3,3, -22,2,2, -31,3,3
```

Comment: [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/61545/cell-phone-keyboard-typing/) (but not the same).

Comment: @JohnE Ah, good catch - That didn't come up in the list of possible dupes as I was entering the question. I hope this is suitably different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Python 2, 423 bytes (no */# support)

```
k='/.@~ABC~DEF~GHI~JKL~MNO~PQRSTUV~WXYZ+~~~ '
d='123456789~0'
g={c:(i/12,i%12/4,i%4)for i,c in enumerate(k)}
g.update(((c,(i/3,i%3,0))for i,c in enumerate(d)))
del g['~']
def f(s):
 s,a=[c for c in s[::-1].upper() if c in g],[]
 q=[1,1,1]
 while s:
  y,x,r=g[s.pop()]
  n,m,_=(9,9,9)if not s else g[s[-1]]
  v=y-q[x]
  q[x]=y
  a+=[(v<0)*'-'+`x+1`+(v!=0)*`abs(v)`]+r*[`x+1`]+(c in k and(y,x)==(n,m))*['P']
 print','.join(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Java, 701

```java
static void main(String a[]){int q[]={1,1,1},w[]={0,0,0},f=9,n=0,p=1,x,y,r,l=0,d;String c,i=String.join(" ",a),o="";i=i.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9/.@*#+ ]+", "").toUpperCase();String[]v="1/.@|4GHI|7PQRS&2ABC|5JKL|8TUV|0 &3DEF|6MNO|9WXYZ".split("&");for(;l<i.length();){c=""+i.charAt(l++);for(x=0;x<3;x++)if(v[x].contains(c)){n=x;String[]b=v[x].split("\\|");for(y=0;y<b.length;y++)if(b[y].contains(c)) {w[x]=y;p=b[y].indexOf(c);}}if(f==n&&q[f]==w[f]){if(i.matches("[^0-9]+"))o+="P,";for(r=0;r<p;r++)o+=(f+1)+",";}else{d=w[n]-q[n];if(d!=0)o+=d;for(r=0;r<p;r++){o=new StringBuilder(o).insert(d==0?o.length():o.length()-1,n+1).toString();d=0;o+=",";}}q[n]=w[n];f=n;}System.out.print(o.replaceAll(",$",""));}}
```

#### Completely unoptimised and ungolfed

A starting point

```java
public class Keypad {

public static void main(String a[]){

    int fingerRow[] = {1,1,1}, nextFingerRow[]=new int[3], finger=-1, nextFinger=0, repeat=1;
    String input = String.join(" ",a), out="";
    input=input.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9/.@*#+ ]+", "").toUpperCase(); //strip nonsense
    System.out.println(input);
    boolean numbersOnly = input.charAt(0)>47 && input.charAt(0)<58;

    String[] columns = "1/.@|4GHI|7PQRS&2ABC|5JKL|8TUV|0 &3DEF|6MNO|9WXYZ".split("&");

    for (int l=0;l<input.length();l++) {
        // current letter
        String letter = ""+input.charAt(l);

        // find finger
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            if (columns[i].contains(letter)) {
                nextFinger = i;
                // find row
                String[] buttons = columns[i].split("\\|");
                for (int j=0; j<buttons.length; j++) {
                    if (buttons[j].contains(letter)) {
                        nextFingerRow[i]=j;
                        repeat=buttons[j].indexOf(letter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // both same && letter? Add Pause.
        if (finger==nextFinger && fingerRow[finger]==nextFingerRow[finger]){
            if (!numbersOnly) out += "P,";
            for (int r=0; r<repeat;r++) {
                out += (finger+1)+",";
            }
        }
        else {
            // work out previous to current
            int distance = nextFingerRow[nextFinger] - fingerRow[nextFinger];
            if(distance!=0) out+=distance;
            // add finger
            for (int r=0; r<repeat;r++) {
                out = new StringBuilder(out).insert(distance==0?out.length():out.length()-1, nextFinger+1).toString();
                distance=0;
                out+=",";
            }
        }
        fingerRow[nextFinger] = nextFingerRow[nextFinger];
        finger = nextFinger;
    }
    System.out.println(out.replaceAll(",$",""));
}
}
```

#### Sample run

```java
CODE GOLF
-21,2,2,3,3,3,-31,P,3,3,23,1,31,3,3,-22,2,2,-31,3,3
```