# KeyPad Code to Text!

Tags: code-golf, string, keyboard

Given a String and an Array as input, your task is to output the text the input String will print when typed on a typical Mobile Keypad. In a Mobile Keypad, a letter is typed by pressing a button n times, where n is the position of where the letter is at on the button's label. So, `22` should output `b`.

[image: Keypad]

---

## Rules

- The Helper Array will contain the Character Map (`["  ",".,!","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"]`). This will be given to save you some bytes.
- The `#` symbol will toggle case. Initial Case will be lower. So `2#3` should output `aD`.
- The `0` will add a space. So, `202` should output `a a`.
- There will be a space () in the input String to start a new letter that is on the same numeric button. For Example to type `aa`, the input String will be `2 2`.
- It is guranteed that the input String will always be a valid KeyPad Code.

---

## Input

You can take input in whatever way your language supports.

---

## Output

You can output the result in any way you want. Function `return` is also allowed.

---

## Test Cases

```
#4440555#666888330#999#66688111 -> "I Love You!"
#6#33777 7779990#222#4477744477778627777111 -> "Merry Christmas!"
#44#27 79990#66#3390#999#332777111 -> "Happy New Year!"
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: [Closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61545/45941)

Comment: I think the capitalization on `year` in the last test case is wrong.

Comment: Do we have to consider looping? Like, 2222->invalid or 2222->b?

Comment: @Maltysen Yes, you are right. I've edited the question. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Out of interest, do `##` or double space need to be handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth - 31 bytes

The new key thing cost me too much.

```
ss.emr!FZk@@QsedthdfndeTrb8cz\#
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ss.emr%21FZk%40%40QsedthdfndeTrb8cz%5C%23&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%22+%22%2C%22.%2C%21%22%2C%22abc%22%2C%22def%22%2C%22ghi%22%2C%22jkl%22%2C%22mno%22%2C%22pqrs%22%2C%22tuv%22%2C%22wxyz%22%5D%0A%234440555%23666888330%23999%2366688111%0A%5B%22+%22%2C%22.%2C%21%22%2C%22abc%22%2C%22def%22%2C%22ghi%22%2C%22jkl%22%2C%22mno%22%2C%22pqrs%22%2C%22tuv%22%2C%22wxyz%22%5D%0A%236%2333777+7779990%23222%234477744477778627777111%0A%5B%22+%22%2C%22.%2C%21%22%2C%22abc%22%2C%22def%22%2C%22ghi%22%2C%22jkl%22%2C%22mno%22%2C%22pqrs%22%2C%22tuv%22%2C%22wxyz%22%5D%0A%2344%2327+79990%2366%233390999332777111&debug=0&input_size=2).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>105</s> 99 bytes

```js
f=
(s,a)=>s.replace(/#| ?((.)\2*)/g,(m,n,d)=>d?(l=a[d][n.length-1],x?l:l.toUpperCase()):(x=!x,''),x=1)

a=['  ','.,!','abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqrs','tuv','wxyz']

F=s=>console.log( f(s,a) )
F('#4440555#666888330#999#66688111')
F('#6#33777 7779990#222#4477744477778627777111');
F('#44#27 79990#66#3390#999#332777111');
```

- 6 bytes off thanks @Neil.

Comment: You can save some bytes by storing the letter in a temporary (e.g. `l`) and then using `c?l:l.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: @Neil. Considering the array is already in lowercase... thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>119</s>  97 bytes

map based solution 119 bytes

```perl6
->$_,\a{my$u=0;[~] map {/'#'/??{$u+^=1;|()}()!!(&lc,&uc)[$u](a[.substr(0,1)].substr(.chars-1,1))},.comb(/(\d)$0*|'#'/)}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#XZHLbtpAFIb3forji2CG@m5jsAwkUjetlHTVTQQ0MvYE3OJLPTaJS@Bh2ufIM@UR6LEpadXF/HMu8/1HM1NzBjtPjwKhxugz41UgCGkD13GyTiquVbkWbotNCFOQACRV0lURNVxFqDF7QF1vEtSv37aoaZajFt9LjltV71Afn5ofUtB69qI8ZjA9aTPlXl2E@7RR6qkZzI9LSMMC9kZf7htXV3ulfvdlagXPhB4IFUXS20Zqr47oXKmXJJzrvF7xqiSmatHlJdGjTVhyzcIaPah6lKcrYpBFTBVz8Nz60sPpIS9hm2SMEwp7ASA1UACUSZIVdTXDK5LJXDZ13V/AcjagXXfBB9DXZv026AqvLz@l15dfcHyLlAl7KlhUsbj1AKJ3qIEPiTMaUDp77Bwvk4I/jQt27r2ZdGDCoX0ucqbV//@Dqn9xDO8D4SDEeca0Cr8wydbBSXZd1xwOh7LneePx2HFM2ff9c2ZZFmgzkD7CTb5jcJfXoiTInuw4o9EIcOFJU7ZtG00wczsdjT273S7wLSvLBt5vyoRXachbB9eVbeQ72mvt/PNQx7H/AT@ERdHAJ/YIdywsRek3)

substitution based solution 97 bytes

```perl6
->$_,\a{my$u=0;S:g/(\d)$0*|./{$0??(&lc,&uc)[$u](a[$0].substr($/.chars-1,1))!!($u+^=$/eq'#')x 0}/}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#jZJLcptAEIb3nKKBKQkU3iAkgl5V2SRVTjbJxiUprjGMJRLxMMPIIrJ8mOQcPpOPoAzIclIpL7KYf3povr@7p4ZRAlvfiEKB8egLoVUoyPoEXWkzDPu0RmxshZ/frkxlEavI6t135a65R9Z0qnQ2kdZhkTpHbKnM8BxZS4Oya1qVCjKNaI1LqtuaraqiqCD25uvYVndgHcyDIKQ1zOJklVRUr3Idb4o1hjFIAJImGZrIFV9HXGNyw3W1Trh@@77hmmY51@K2pHyr2Jbr3a7@IYWNZyfKYwLjY9v/Ar/WvvFa8//ROzLJLR/9eYLjTV7CJskIVVTYCwCpyQUAjZKsYNWED6OM5rJlGMEClpPeVG3TC9qDrj7pNkH74enxp/T0@AseXiI0IruCRBWJGxNQjF6DmqHQFKkBtf4883AuFT4nztgp92LSggmF5maUE639e/Wq9gfn4VUoHIQ4z4he8eeQZKvwKHueZ/X7fdn3/eFw6LqWHATB6WTbNugTkD7ARb4lcJkzURJkX3bdwWAAfPE/LdlxHG7CT16rg6HvNNsZ/kjKsoZ36zKhVYpp4@B5ssP5lvYbu@BU1HWdv8D3uChq@ETu4JLgUpR@Aw)

### Expanded:

```perl6
->     # pointy block lambda

  $_,  # input string
  \a   # helper array

{

  my $u = 0;

  S                        # substitute (implicit against ｢$_｣)
  :global
  /

    | (\d) $0*             # digit followed by same digit
    | .                    # everything else

  /{

    $0                     # is ｢$0｣ set (digit)


    ??                     # if so then
        (&lc,&uc)[$u](     # call either ｢lc｣ or ｢uc｣

          a[$0]            # get the value from the input array
          .substr(         # select the correct character
            $/.chars - 1,
            1
          )

        )


    !!
        (
          $u +^= $/ eq '#' # numeric xor $u if ｢#｣ was matched
        ) x 0              # string repeated zero times (empty string)

  }/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6 - 124 bytes

Golfed:

```
f=h=>a=>(o=c="")+a.match(/#|(.)\1*/g).forEach(e=>e==" "?0:e=="#"?c=!c:(n=h[e[0]][e.length-1])*(o+=c?n.toUpperCase():n))?o:0;
```

```js
f=h=>a=>(o=c="")+a.match(/#|(.)\1*/g).forEach(e=>e==" "?0:e=="#"?c=!c:(n=h[e[0]][e.length-1])*(o+=c?n.toUpperCase():n))?o:0;

console.log(f(["  ",".,!","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"])("#4440555#666888330#999#66688111"));
console.log(f(["  ",".,!","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"])("#6#33777 7779990#222#4477744477778627777111"));
console.log(f(["  ",".,!","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"])("#44#27 79990#66#3390999332777111"));
```

Ungolfed:

```
f=(a,h)=>{
    //out string
    o="";
    //uppercase or lowercase (initialized as "" and then inverted in golfed version)
    c=0;
    //split it into array of instructions, which are sets of repeated characters, or # solely alone
    a.match(/#|(.)\1*/g).forEach((e)=>{
        e==" "?0:
            e=="#" ? (c=!c) : ( ()=>{ //lambda added because two statements ungolfed, multiplied in the golfed version
                    n=h[e[0]][e.length-1];
                    o+=c?n.toUpperCase():n;
                })()
    })
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 301 bytes

```
(a,b)=>{u="l";p=[];r="";a.split``.map((c,i)=>p.push(c!=a[i-1]?" "+c:c));p.join``.trim().replace('   ', ' ').split` `.map(l=>{if(l=="#"){u=(u=="l"?b.forEach((y,j)=>b[j]=y.toUpperCase())||"u":b.forEach((y,j)=>b[j]=y.toLowerCase())||"l")}else{if(l!="  "){r+=b[+l[0]][l.length-1]}else{r+=" "}}});return r}
```

```js
f=(a,b)=>{u="l";p=[];r="";a.split``.map((c,i)=>p.push(c!=a[i-1]?" "+c:c));p.join``.trim().replace('   ', ' ').split` `.map(l=>{if(l=="#"){u=(u=="l"?b.forEach((y,j)=>b[j]=y.toUpperCase())||"u":b.forEach((y,j)=>b[j]=y.toLowerCase())||"l")}else{if(l!="  "){r+=b[+l[0]][l.length-1]}else{r+=" "}}});return r}

console.log(f("#4440555#666888330#999#66688111 ",["  ",".,!","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"]));
console.log(f("#6#33777 7779990#222#4477744477778627777111",["  ",".,!","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"]));
console.log(f("#44#27 79990#66#3390#999#332777111",["  ",".,!","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"]));
```

I know this is very long, but this is the best I can.

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 60 bytes

```
Í /|
Í¨ä©¨±*©/½a[submatch(1)][len(submatch(2))]
Í|
ò/#
g~$x
```

(There's an unprintable `½<Ctrl+r>a`)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#PYw7EoJAEERzQk@AjAFYlsDussBZKAJEBH/4AfyV5Q24hYGEmpssB8MBqgzmdfVM9zR1Ket3qS7Fq36KSrzEeywqXXwHgZcVs22Qh4lqar63iVL1vyCa5mMHex8dpPgxujQNMMYMy7KAc@44DqUGuK7bO9M0JeBAqW3bMg4eDCCEYAcd62g7nLTSZRkDgskux9ui23@jlECfaTxFVibKdDJEBrMQOY8WyDhZIlfrDXKb7pD7wzFDyYsT8ny53hT/Bw)

#### Explain

```
Í /|                                          #Replace all " " with "|"
Í¨ä©¨±*©                                      #Replace all (\d)(\1*)
        /½                                    #With =
          ^Ra                                 #(Inserts the passed array)
             [submatch(1)][len(submatch(2))]  #Index into the array
Í|                                            #Replace all "|" with "" (second ò implied)
ò   ò                                         #Recursively (until breaking)
 /#                                           #Go to the next #
g~$                                           #Toggle case until the of the line
   x                                          #Delete current char (#)
```