# Full Width Text

Tags: code-golf, string

Full width text is text that has a space after every character, including the last one. For instance, the first sentence of this question becomes:

```
F u l l   w i d t h   t e x t   i s   t e x t   t h a t   h a s   a   s p a c e   a f t e r   e v e r y   c h a r a c t e r ,   i n c l u d i n g   t h e   l a s t   o n e .
```

Write a program that takes a line in text from standard input and outputs it as full-width text to standard out.

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=75979,OVERRIDE_USER=52353;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: So, if I understand, we can't take input as a function parameter (or output as a return value)?

Comment: @NathanMerrill Yes, that's correct.

Comment: *Usually* you should allow functions too, or you exclude a lot of languages (e.g. JavaScript).

Comment: And the challenge would be more interesting if you had to detect whether the text was full-width and then toggle its full-width-ness, but that's just a suggestion, and there are already answers so you can't, but it's an idea for a new question...

Comment: True. Good suggestions, thanks :)

Comment: We have a few [defaults for I/O](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447) that are based on community consensus. While you are entitled to override them, insisting on STDIN/STDOUT for I/O invalidates a bunch of answers (which assumed that the defaults apply) and make the task downright impossible in other languages (they *don't have* standard streams).

Comment: Ｔｈａｔ　ｉｓ　ｎｏｔ　ｗｈａｔ　[ｆｕｌｌｗｉｄｔｈ　ｔｅｘｔ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms)　ｉｓ．

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft is right. Full Width text is about underlying character encoding ( 2 bytes encoded ) required by some language ( i.e. ideograms ). In Unicode the notion of half and full size is called [Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block)

Comment: I know this is a little late, but what are the rules regarding accepting `stdin` until someone pressed Ctrl-D to signify `EOF`?

Comment: @LudovicFrérot Actually, these are not ideograms, these are chinese english letters.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer : what the heck is "chinese english letters" ? Chinese doesn't use any of the Latin, Cyrillic, or any other alphabet. Heck they don't even use an alphabet at all. Those codepoints probably exists for convenience of rendering purposes, but they're very much still Latin-based letters through and through

Answer (score 29):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s> <s>3</s> 2 bytes

Thanks to *Dennis* for saving 2 bytes. Also thanks to *FryAmTheEggman* for saving 1 byte. Code:

```
p⁶
```

Explanation:

```
p⁶   # Cartesian product with the input and the space character.
```

Uses the [Jelly encoding](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page).

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=cOKBtg&input=&args=RnVsbCB3aWR0aCB0ZXh0IGlzIHRleHQgdGhhdCBoYXMgYSBzcGFjZSBhZnRlciBldmVyeSBjaGFyYWN0ZXIsIGluY2x1ZGluZyB0aGUgbGFzdCBvbmUu)

Comment: You don't need `s1`.

Comment: @Dennis Oh thanks! I didn't know that.

Comment: ⁶ takes up three bytes in UTF-8.

Comment: @JessSmith Jelly uses its own code page: https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md

Comment: @AandN Put it in the answer, not a comment.

Comment: @mbomb007 It's right in the header.

Comment: @AandN No, you should say in your answer that it has its own code page. Especially since it's a newer language, so people don't know yet.

Comment: Woah, that was fast! (Also, should the 6 be two bytes since it's Unicode?)

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Jelly uses it's own [custom encoding](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md).

Comment: @AandN OK, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't this take input from the command-line arguments rather than STDIN?

Comment: @Challenger5 Fixing it is trivial: `ɠp⁶`

Comment: For the record, the atom `K` was added on Aug 12 '16, later than the challenge, that does exactly what the challenge asks for.

Comment: Invalid because it doesn't use STDIN.

Answer (score 28):

## Python 3.5, 18 bytes

```python
print(*input(),'')
```

This works because [`print`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#print)'s default separator is single space.

Comment: `print(*input(),end=' ')` would be portable, but it's not very golfy...

Comment: MFW the first use of my PEP I see in the wild is on Code Golf.

Comment: Does this have a space after the last character?

Answer (score 17):

## [Hexagony](http://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), <s>21</s> <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

**Code:**

Saved a *lot* of bytes thanks to *FryAmTheEggman*. Code:

```
P,<0/*;@.>
```

Or in a more readable form:

```
  P , <
 0 / * ;
@ . > . .
 . . . .
  . . .
```

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=UCw8MC8qO0AuPg&input=RnVsbCB3aWR0aCB0ZXh0IGlzIHRleHQgdGhhdCBoYXMgYSBzcGFjZSBhZnRlciBldmVyeSBjaGFyYWN0ZXIsIGluY2x1ZGluZyB0aGUgbGFzdCBvbmUu)

**Explanation:**

The Hexagony program starts at the top-left corner, immediately setting the memory edge to the ASCII value of `P`, which is 80. After that, we can see that the following path is taken:

[image]

We can see that the path taken is: `P,<;.P/0....;*/>`. After the `P`, we take a byte of user input. If this is empty, the following branch (`<`) would direct us to the North East. If the input is non-empty, the branch directs us to the South East. After that, we output the user input using `;`. We set the memory edge back to `P`, which is 80. The zero followed by the mirror is then concatenated to our number, resulting into 800. This is then outputted using the `;` command, but first it is taken modulo 256, resulting into 32, which is the space character. After that, we reset the memory edge using the `*` command and return to loop over the rest of the user input. When we're done with the user input, the path is directed to the North East:

[image]

This basically goes to the `@` command, which terminates the program.

Using [Timwi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/668/timwi)'s amazing [*HexagonyColorer*](https://github.com/Timwi/HexagonyColorer) for making the diagrams.

Comment: Uh, I was golfing while you edited. Oops. 10: `P,<0/*;@.>`

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Hahaha, let's make a new explanation then :p.

Comment: `P,<<>0;@>*` is also 10, but unfortunately I don't think it helps in shaving off another byte.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Oh, that's a shame. I doubt if it's possible to shave off another byte, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: Is HexagonyColorer now animated?

Answer (score 13):

### Haskell, 11 bytes

```
((:" ")=<<)
```

Usage example: `((:" ")=<<) "Code Golf"` -> `"C o d e   G o l f "`.

Map each character `c` to a two element list `[c, space]` and concatenate everything into a single list.

Comment: Interesting that Haskell and Jelly are kind of doing the same thing here, since the list monad acts similarly to a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 9):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 5

```
.
$&
```

Note the space at the end of the second line.

`$&` is equivalent to `$0`.  Thanks to @mbomb007 for [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx#EntireMatch).

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LgokJiA&input=RnVsbCB3aWR0aCB0ZXh0IGlzIHRleHQgdGhhdCBoYXMgYSBzcGFjZSBhZnRlciBldmVyeSBjaGFyYWN0ZXIsIGluY2x1ZGluZyB0aGUgbGFzdCBvbmUu)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I prefer to use `$0`. It's the same thing, but more common.

Comment: Here's a useful reference to go along with Retina's wiki: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx#EntireMatch

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, 20 Bytes

Simple, I just wish that Array.join added the space to the end so I could save 3 bytes.

```
s=>[...s,``].join` `
```

Comment: ```[...s,``].join` ` ``` perhaps?

Comment: Even better `[...s,,].join` ...

Comment: @edc65 Doesn't work in latest Firefox or Chrome? I just get the `join` function as the return, as I would expect.

Comment: @Mwr247 after the join you must put the rest of your code, that's why I put ellipsis (...). It's just 1 byte saving

Comment: @edc65 may have been too lazy to work out how to type the `\` \`` in a comment.

Comment: (mobile can’t paste?) 19 bytes: `s=>[...s,,].join` ``

Comment: @Makonede I probably did mean that, three years ago.

Answer (score 5):

### Java, 132 (System.in) or 99 (Program argument) bytes

Can you feel the overhead tonight?

```java
class F{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().replaceAll("(.)", "$0 "));}}
class W{public static void main(String[]a){for(char c:a[0].toCharArray())System.out.print(c+" ");}}
```

[shooqie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51530/shooqie) figured out [a 6 byte shorter way to do this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76010/51825) but I won't steal their approach. I've used it with the STDIN and lambda versions, however.

28 characters for a lambda but that doesn't meet the program requirement.

```java
s->s.replaceAll("(.)","$0 ")
```

Comment: The question specified that the input must be from STDIN.

Comment: I could add one for you, if that's ok.

Comment: I've added a STDIN version now (and used the clever regexplace shooqie figured out).

Comment: [No need for parentheses in your regex.](https://tio.run/##LYyxCsIwEEB/JQSHBDS4O7k4uXUUhzM99Or1UpJrq5R@e@zg9ODxeB1McOjad62RoRRzWYbxwRRNUdANU6LW9EDiGs0kz9sd/NJ8i2If0qhh2KQ6wdl02ymMShyaCCKY3T8j8UHwo1cSdD5kHBginpmdDXZvd0djvT@ta60vZE5mTpnbHw) Also removed an extra space between arguments to `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 5):

## Awk, 7 bytes

(4 characters code + 3 characters command line option.)

```awk
NF++
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ awk -F '' 'NF++' <<< 'Full width text.'
F u l l   w i d t h   t e x t .
```

(There is some disagreement on what should be included in the command line option count. I included what is actually passed to the `awk` interpreter: “-”, “F” and a separator between “F” and the empty string parameter. See below what I mean.)

```
bash-4.3$ od -tax1 /proc/`pidof awk`/cmdline 
0000000   a   w   k nul   -   F nul nul   N   F   +   + nul
         61  77  6b  00  2d  46  00  00  4e  46  2b  2b  00
                         ╰────────╯
```

Answer (score 5):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to @Sp3000*

```
i:0(?;o 'o
```

[**Try it here**](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/RfSiCr7a5R6wPcPTk). Click the link, then *Submit*, then type some input and press *Give*, and finally run the program with *Start* or *Run without animation*.

#### Explanation

```
i       read a character
:       duplicate
0(      is it less than 0?
?;      if so: end program. Else:
o       output read character
 '      push all chars until matching (same) quote. Top character is a space
o       output that character, which is a space. Go back to the beginning
```

Comment: `i:0(?;o 'o` for 10

Comment: In fact, `io 'o` works too, erroring out.

Comment: @Sp3000 Thanks! I'll go for the no-error version (maybe you want to submit yours?). I forgot you can input chars directly. How does the unmatched quote work? Does it always pick the preceding char?

Comment: `'` just wraps around, pushing chars until it finds another `'` to close it. In this case the opening and closing `'`s are the same char and most of the source code is pushed, but the top char would just be space since it was pushed last.

Comment: @Sp3000 Got it. So _that_'s also cyclical. Thanks a lot for the suggestion and explanation!

Comment: My first ><> answer!

Comment: @CAD97 This is one of those cases where there's a discrepancy between `fishlanguage.com` and the official Python interpreter (which @Dennis has kindly added to [Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/)). In the official Python interpreter, trying to output a char with a negative code point terminates with an error.

Comment: Context please?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy I had a comment for about 15 seconds saying that the online interpreter printed `-1` as the char `0xFF` instead of terminating. I deleted the comment because SE didn't show the character I copy/paste'd.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, 92

```
class T{public static void main(String[]A){System.out.print(A[0].replaceAll("(.)","$0 "));}}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 10 bytes

Cubix is a 2 dimensional language developed by @ETHproductions where the commands are wrapped onto a cube.  [Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix)

```
@.?wi^\oSo
```

This maps onto a cube with edge length 2

```
    @ .
    ? w
i ^ \ o S o . .
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

Starts with a input `i`.  The flow is redirected north `^` to the top face.  `?` If the value is negative turn left to finish `@`, zero carries on into shift right `w` or positive turn right then reflect left `\`.  Output character with a trailing space `oSo`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix/), 9 bytes

```
@./.i?>So
```

[**See it work online!**](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIEAgLgogICAgLyAuCmkgPyA+IFMgbyAuIC4gLgouIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgIC4gLgogICAgLiAuCg==&input=Q3ViaXg=&speed=20)

Cubix is a language in which the instructions are mapped out onto the face of a cube. This program forms the following cube net:

```
    @ .
    / . 
i ? > S o . . .
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

The instruction pointer begins at `i`, which takes another character-code from input and pushes it to the stack. If there is no more input left to be taken, the `?` turns the IP left, where it hits `/`, and is reflected upwards to `@`, which terminates the program.

However, if there is input left, the value will be a character code. As all<sup>1</sup> character codes are positive, the `?` makes the IP turn right, where it wraps all the way around the cube, passing `o` on the way which outputs the char. It then hits `/` which makes it loop back around to `>So`, which pushes and prints a space. The IP carries on west until wrapping around back to the `i`, back to the start of the main loop.

<sup>1</sup> *If the character is a null byte, it will ignore the `?` and carry on straight ahead, simply outputting a single space.*

---

Of course, there's only so much a written explanation can do, so I highly recommend you view this in the [online interpreter](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIEAgLgogICAgLyAuCmkgPyA+IFMgbyAuIC4gLgouIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgIC4gLgogICAgLiAuCg==&input=Q3ViaXg=&speed=20). There's a "speed" option, which allows you to view the execution as slow or fast as you like.

Comment: you can save a byte with `@.Uoi?So`

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

Ties Jelly!

```
0\
```

[Try it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=0%5C&i=Full+width+text+is+text+that+has+a+space+after+every+character%2C+including+the+last+one.)

All this does is push `0` to the stack and zip the string from standard input with it, repeating the 0 as necessary. In Stax, code point 0 in a string is usually converted to 32 (space).

This is short enough that packing it into `ûT` does nothing but reduce readability.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, <s>5</s> 4 bytes

*Thanks to @FryAmTheEggman for saving a byte.*

```
s*zd
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Bjdzd&input=Full+width+text+is+text+that+has+a+space+after+every+character%2C+including+the+last+one.&debug=0).

Comment: Jesus hecking christ how the heck

Comment: Alternative 4-byter: `s+R;`

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 7 bytes

```
tnZ"v1e
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dG5aInYxZQ&input=J1RoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0Jw)

#### Explanation

```
t    % implicitly take input string and duplicate it
n    % number of elements
Z"   % string with that many spaces
v    % concatenate vertically (2xN array, where N is input length)
1e   % reshape into 1 row. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 3):

### Seriously, 7 bytes

```
' ;,@j+
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=JyA7LEBqKw&input=ImZvbyBiYXIi)

Man, that required ending space added 3 additional bytes. Without it, `,' j` would work for 4.

Explanation:

```
' ;,@j+
' ;      push two copies of a single space
   ,@    push input, swap
     j+  join on spaces, append a space
```

Answer (score 3):

## 05AB1E, 4 bytes

```
Sð«J
```

[Try it online.](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=U8OwwqtK&input=dGVzdA)

### Explanation

```
Sð«J

S     split string into a list
 ð«   append a space to each element
   J  join
```

Comment: `ðâJ` non-competing.

Comment: @Kevin That doesn't output the trailing space.

Answer (score 3):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 5 bytes

```
?=?\
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '?=?\ ' <<< 'Full width text.'
F u l l   w i d t h   t e x t .
```

Comment: I haven't seen this language before. Link to the interpreter?

Comment: Sorry. Added hyperlink to the post title. Quite old, but sadly, Google can efficiently help finding it only if you know that the name comes from “general purpose macro processor”.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

*1 byte fewer thanks to @FryAmTheEggman*

```
lSf+
```

[**Try it online!**](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=bFNmKw&input=VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q)

#### Explanation

```
l     e# read line
Sf+   e# map "concatenation" (+) with a space (S) as extra parameter
      e# implicitly display characters in the stack
```

Answer (score 3):

## GolfScript, 6 bytes

```
' ':n*
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=JyAnOm4q&input=RnVsbCB3aWR0aCB0ZXh0IGlzIHRleHQgdGhhdCBoYXMgYSBzcGFjZSBhZnRlciBldmVyeSBjaGFyYWN0ZXIsIGluY2x1ZGluZyB0aGUgbGFzdCBvbmUu)

Answer (score 3):

## C, 56 Bytes (as program argument), 46 Bytes (from stdin)

```c
main(int a,char**b){while(*b[1])printf("%c ",*b[1]++);}
```

Plain old C answer. Once compiled, the program needs to be called with a string as it's first parameter, a string with spaces needs to be enclosed in quotes. For the example in the start post:

```c
./prog "Full width text is text that has a space after every character, including the last one."
```

Which will output

```c
F u l l   w i d t h   t e x t   i s   t e x t   t h a t   h a s   a   s p a c e   a f t e r   e v e r y   c h a r a c t e r ,   i n c l u d i n g   t h e   l a s t   o n e .
```

Solution that reads directly from stdin.

```c
main(c){while(c=~getchar())printf("%c ",~c);}
```

One byte less thanks to @FryAmTheEggman

Comment: The requirements are a little murky, but I believe you have to read the input from `stdin` rather than taking it as an argument.  Also, here is a page with some useful tips for further golfing in C: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2203/13877

Comment: @Josh Does it count as a parameter to main? Because otherwise, the Java answer will be just as wrong, and not so sure about the Haskell one either.

Comment: Either is fine we like our I/O to be friendly :) But I do believe using `getchar()` is shorter. Also you don't need the include for most C compilers.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I left the include in to be completely compliant, I can only test with gcc. As long as gcc-only is fine, yeah, shaving the include is alright.

Comment: Generally, if it works with [Ideone](https://ideone.com/9f0N75) it's ok :)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman How about non terminating? Because that's the only way a getchar version will be shorter. That sort of stops to count as a proper program for me :D

Comment: Really? I think I have a shorter way with `getchar`, but generally no that's not alright unless specifically allowed.

Comment: I'm an idiot, that's all.

Comment: Your non terminating answer can be made to terminate by adding `~` before `c`s assignment and usage, to convert `EOF` to `0`.

Comment: Languages are defined by their implementation on PPCG. If it works without the include statement (and it does with GCC), you don't need it.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I realised just as I hit edit, but somehow my latest edit reverted instead of adding the functioning version. Hence my comment about being an idiot ;)
Dennis, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You can save some bytes with `main(a,b)char**b;{...}`

Answer (score 3):

## brainfuck, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

Simple example using the [shortest known 32](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants#32) for the space character(s).

```
,[.>>-[-[-<]>>+<]>-.,]
```

[**Try it online**](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LFsuPj4tWy1bLTxdPj4rPF0-LS4sXQ&input=VGVzdA)

Comment: `,[.>>-[-[-<]>>+<]>-.,]` saves two bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## R, 36 bytes

```
cat(strsplit(readline(),"")[[1]],"")
```

Example:

```
> cat(strsplit(readline(),"")[[1]],"")
Hello R!
H e l l o   R !
```

Comment: You don't need `sep=" "`, so this can be much shorter: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfk5lUlFhUqZGbWpKRn1Ks@T85sUQjNUejuKSouCAns0SjODkxT0NHSUkThMHEfyWP1JycfB2F8PyinBRFpf8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [WhoScript](http://esolangs.org/wiki/WhoScript) 38 bytes

```
1v;pr;e;#0 1;-;i;t=;ti;o;tl;" ";d;>;pf
```

Works best when the string is given at the command line, but it can be done one character at a time in real time as well.

Ungolfed:

```
time_vortex
  psychic_paper read
  duplicate
  # 0 1
  -
  integer
  TARDIS =
  TARDIS if
      opening
  TARDIS landing
  # 20
paradox
pop
psychic_paper flush
```

Answer (score 3):

#### PHP, 39 bytes

```
echo join(' ',str_split($argv[1])).' ';
```

Run it from the command line

```
php fullwidth.php "Full width text is text that has a space after every character, including the last one."
```

https://eval.in/541179

Answer (score 3):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth/), 10 bytes

```
<.23.%):,>
```

This terminates with an error, but the error messages goes to STDERR.

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=PC4yMy4lKTosPg&input=RnVsbCB3aWR0aCB0ZXh0)

#### Explanation

This is one of the rare cases where a completely linear program is feasible. The loop is achieved via the source code modification commands `<` and `>`, which works because after each iteration we know that the stack is empty again.

`<` cyclically shifts the entire line one cell to the left, so we end up with:

```
.23.%):,><
```

This takes the instruction pointer (IP) with it so the IP is now at the right end of the code and has to move left. Next, the `>` does the opposite modification so it shifts the source code back to

```
<.23.%):,>
```

Now we execute a single iteration (from right to left), before everything starts over:

```
,    Read a character code from STDIN, or -1 at EOF.
:)   Duplicate and increment.
%    Modulo. At EOF this will attempt a division by zero and terminate. Otherwise, we
     have n % (n+1) = n, so we're left with the input character again.
.    Print it back to STDOUT.
32   Turn the top of the stack into a 32.
.    Print it as well (a space).
```

Answer (score 3):

## C, 50 bytes

Little bit of `main()` recursion :)

```c
main(c){~(c=getchar())?printf("%c ",c),main():0;}
```

[Try it online!](http://ideone.com/xM3xVg) - If using this on your own machine, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to signify EOF.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>27</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```python
lambda x:' '.join(x)+' '
```

Shorter than Raffi's answer...

*-1 thanks to 60919 (FlipTack).*

Comment: If functions are allowed then `lambda x:' '.join(x)+' '` is 1 byte shorter.

Answer (score 3):

### APL, 5 bytes

```
∊2∘↑¨
```

This takes 2 items for each character in the string, with the effect of adding a space

To make it a program that takes stdin, it's the same number of bytes:

```
∊2↑¨⎕
```

Try it [here](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%u220A2%u2218%u2191%A8%20%u22C4%20f%20%27Hello%20World%21%27&run).

Answer (score 3):

## [Threead](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Threead), <s>45</s> 16 Bytes non-competing.

```
  B[coB]
32c   o
```

Takes input via STDIN.

The first Line/Tape simply reads bytes from STDIN, and writes them. The second line, initially stores a space via `32c`, then at the same time that the next character is being read, outputs that space.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/threead#@6@g4BSdnO8Uy2VslKygoJD//7@jk7MLAA)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 31 bytes

```php
<?=chunk_split($argv[1],1," ");
```

takes input from command line argument.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 5 bytes

```
dm+s_
```

Explanation:

```
d     -    load ' ' onto the stack
 m+   -   map(add, eval_input_or_not(), " ")
   s  -  "".join(^)
    _ - ^[::-1]
```

At the moment Pyke has a bug where if map is given a string, it reverses it :(

#### Or with a new fixed version, 3 bytes

```
dL+
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=dL%2B&input=Full+width+text+is+text+that+has+a+space+after+every+character%2C+including+the+last+one.)

```
left_map(input(), " ", add)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>24</s> 15 bytes

```
gsub /./,'\0 '
```

Requires the `-p` flag (byte added).

Thanks to [xsot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45268/xsot) for 9 bytes!

Comment: Using `-p` saves 8 bytes

Comment: @xsot Thanks, I didn't even know that flag existed!

Comment: I didn't realise you could omit the parentheses without confusing the interpreter. Looks like the comma operator isn't as overloaded the way I expected.

Comment: @xsot Comma's not an operator in Ruby. Parenthesis are frequently optional, except in certain contexts.

Answer (score 2):

### C, 48 bytes

```c
main(c){for(c=8192;read(0,&c,1);write(1,&c,2));}
```

[Try it online](https://ideone.com/z4poVU)

- `main(c)` declares the `main` function that takes one argument `c`.
  If the data type is not specified, everything is an `int`.
  Therefore `c` is an `int` variable.
- The `main` routine consists of one `for` statement, `for(…);`.
  The body of the `for` loop is empty, everything happens inside the control header.
- `c=8192` initialize `c` to the value `32 * 256`.
  `32` is the ordinal value of a space character.
  `256` shifts the value 8 bits to the left (more significant places).
- `read(0,&c,1)` reads `1` Byte from `STDIN` (`0`) to the address of `c` (`&c`).
  This command returns a successful status as long as there is input to read.
- Provided the `read` is successful, `write(1,&c,2)` writes `2` Bytes that are stored at the address of `c` to `STDOUT` (`1`).

Answer (score 2):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 11 bytes

```
32@
 :,
 ..
```

This is an 11-byte answer which terminates without an error – see [@MartinBüttner's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76096/21487) for a 10-byte answer which terminates with an error. [Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=MzJACiA6LAogLi4&input=RnVsbCB3aWR0aCB0ZXh0)

Starting from the top-left, we have the following setup step:

```
32        Turn a zero at the bottom of the stack into 32 (space)
```

Then we turn right at the `2`, entering the following tight loop:

```
:          Duplicate top of stack (space)
,          Read char from STDIN
.          Output char
.          Output space
```

This loop repeats until `,` reads EOF, which pushes -1 to the top of the stack. The -1 makes us turn left into the `@`, terminating the program.

---

Here are two additional error-free 11-byte solutions, by Martin:

#### Extra version A

```
  3
.:2
.,@
```

This version is the same as the above, but rotated 90 degrees. We still start on  the `3`, since this is the first valid instruction in reading order.

#### Extra version B

```
^,.
@:.
2
3
```

This version is effectively the same as the previous two, but uses an initial `^` to rotate the first column upon running the program, such that the board becomes:

```
@,.
2:.
3
^
```

After this, the code is the same as the original, except rotated 90 degrees in the other direction.

Answer (score 2):

### Befunge-93, 12 bytes

```
~:1+!#@_, ",
```

Tested using [this online interpreter](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html).

```
~                           Read char
 :1+!                       Push (char == -1)
     #@_                    Halt if so, i.e. on EOF
        ,                   Output char
          "~:0`!#@_, "      Push the chars between the quotes, one by one
                      ,     Output the top char, i.e. space
```

Comment: Wow, sleek usage of  `"` and wrap-around

Comment: [-1 Byte](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X6nOylBbUdkhXkfn//@S1OISAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Sed, 8 bytes

```
's/$*/ /g'
```

Can be run from bash as

```
$ sed 's/$*/ /g' <<< "Full Width Text."
```

Outputs

```
 F u l l   w i d t h   t e x t .
```

Comment: Nice answer, but i think you mean '/g/ in the test case not '/f'. +1 though.

Comment: Thank you, 'f' is right next to 'g' on the dvorak keyboard

Comment: My understanding is that a leading space is not permitted.

Comment: I concur with @Neil. The challenge specifically mentions a trailing space. Therefore the `sed` command must be something like `s/./& /g`, which is still 8 Bytes nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

## [beeswax](https://github.com/m-lohmann/BeeswaxEsolang.jl), 20 bytes

```
p?Cy ?<~1V_
>` `Ag'b
```

Example:

```
julia> beeswax("Full Width Text.bswx")
sHello, World!
H e l l o ,   W o r l d !
Program finished!
```

Explanation:

```
             lstack    gstack

          _  [0,0,0]•  []•                          create bee
         V   [0,0,0]•  [72,101,108,108,111,10]•     read in string to gstack
        1    [0,0,1]•                               lstack 1st=1
       ~     [0,1,0]•                               flip lstack 1st and 2nd
      <      [0,0,0]•                           (1) redirect to left
     ?       [0,1,0]•  [72,101,108,108,111]•        pop gstack top value (\n)
   y         [0,1,0]•  [101,108,108,111,72]•        rotate gstack down by lstack[-,steps,depth]•
                                                    depth=0 defaults to full stack length
  C                    STDOUT='H'                   print gstack top value as Char to STDOUT
 ?                     [101,108,108,111]•           pop gstack top value
p                                                   redirect to lower left
>                                                   redirect to right
 ` `                   STDOUT=' '                   print space char to STDOUT
    A                  [101,108,108,111,4]•         push gstack length on top of gstack
     g       [0,1,4]•                               lstack 1st=gstack top
      '                                             skip next if lstack 1st=0
       b                                            redirect to upper left
      <                                             loop back to (1)
     ?                 [101,108,108,111]•
   y         [0,1,4]•  [108,108,111,101]•
  C                    STDOUT='e'
 ?                     [108,108,111]•
p
>` `                   STDOUT=' '

.                          .                             .
.                          .                             .
.                          .                             .
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, 7 bytes

```
32HY(1e
```

[**Try it Online!**](https://tio.run/##JctBCoMwFEXRrbxZHIig3YN0Cx0@4tcEflNJfmxdfRQ6upzBfdO0tcf0fHWjtObmqopvXCzA5GeI5V8LNAQWEGWnF3A1yZBD8gkfmOlv94jJa11i2u5DoCyGT5LBXQ)

**Explanation**

```
    % Implicitly grab input as a string
32  % Number literal (ASCII for ' ')
H   % Clipboard H contains 2 by default
Y(  % Fill the second "row" with spaces
1e  % Force everything onto one row. Due to MATLAB being row-major, this inserts the spaces
    % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), 41 bytes

```
|*
*
`tape`(turn +< |=(@ (cat 3 +< ' ')))
```

Takes advantage of not having to specify the tape of a wet gate (`|*`), and that arguments are places at `+<` to prevent having to name them.

There are actually two different types of strings in Hoon: tapes, and cords. tapes are `(list @tD)`, while cords are simply `@t`.
Think the difference between a vector and an array: tapes can be indexed into and manipulated easily, while cords are "static" and basically just bignums.

This entry maps over the characters in the tape it gets as input, and adds on the value of `' '` to the end of the atom and then casts the result back to a tape.

Technically, this should probably be a type error: tape is a list of characters, and we are stuffing two in the space of only one. Luckily, while Hoon has syntax to say what you should expect the size of an atom to be, it doesn't actually *enforce* that expectation. Even slamming a too-big atom with a specific sized verification gate doesn't give back the default value like it should. Naturally, we abuse this and it even prints correctly in the console, as long as you don't try to full-width text any UTF-8 characters.

Usage:

```
> %.  "Full width text is text that has a space after every character, including the last one."
  |*
  *
  `tape`(turn +< |=(@ (cat 3 +< ' ')))
"F u l l   w i d t h   t e x t   i s   t e x t   t h a t   h a s   a   s p a c e   a f t e r   e v e r y   c h a r a c t e r ,   i n c l u d i n g   t h e   l a s t   o n e . "
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 137 bytes

```cs
Func<string,string>f=(a)=>{return string.Concat(a.ToCharArray().SelectMany(x=>(new char[] {' '}),(x, y)=>x.ToString()+y.ToString()));};
```

doing a console on it gives result : Console.WriteLine(f("arnab bhattacharya"));
a r n a b   b h a t t a c h a r y a

Comment: It's been a while since I've used C#, but I don't believe you need the `Func<string,string>f=` part - we allow anonymous functions, so long as they can be captured and called.

Comment: @Mego I think he needs to provide datatypes, and he cannot provide them otherwise.

Comment: You should read the [C# golfing tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c) thread. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Carrot](https://github.com/kritixilithos/Carrot), 13 bytes, non-competing

```
#^//./gS" "^
```

(note trailing space in code)

[Try it online!](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/)

(to be able to see the trailing space in the output, open up the JS console and select the outputted text in the console output)

#### Explanation

Note: the "stack" is actually just a string (not an array) in Carrot

```
#^                        // pushes the input `#` to the stack, now the stack == input
  /                       // split on:
   /./g                   //  every character in the stack
```

Now the program is in arrayMode, meaning that the stack is now an array (or stackA to be more precise)

```
       S" "               // join on spaces
```

Now we got spaces after every character except for the last one

```
           ^<space>       // append a space to the stack
```

And then the stack is implicitly outputted

Comment: I just accidentally posted this solution without seeing yours. Is there no way to convert to array mode with `A` by splitting on nothing so `Hi` becomes `[ "H", "i" ]`? I though no argument would do it or a space but I was wrong.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Another one of the reasons I am doing the rewrite of Carrot, the current interpreter does a terrible job of parsing and everything is just a bunch of hacks taped very loosely... In the new interpreter, `A` is planned take a string as an argument, where this string can be of any length, in which case what you are suggesting *should* work.

Answer (score 2):

## C++ (gcc), <strike>120</strike> <strike>133</strike> 77 bytes

```c
#import<iostream>
int main(){char c;while(std::cin.get(c))std::cout<<c<<" ";}
```

Thanks to my father, who showed me a nifty trick for getting the characters directly from the input stream... and in turn almost halfed my byte count!

Old solution below using getline and joining substrings:

```c
#import<iostream>
int i;int main(){std::string s,n;std::getline(std::cin,n);for(;i<n.size();i++){s+=n.substr(i,1)+" ";}std::cout<<s;}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkztyC/qMQmM7@4pCg1MdeOKzOvRCE3MTNPQ7M6OSOxSCHZujwjMydVo7gkxcoqOTNPLz21RCNZUxPCzy8tsbFJtrFRUlCyrv3/PyS1uEQBRBgpODo5u7i6uSsYGhmbmJoBAA)

My very first try on golfing. Feel free to give suggestions.

Comment: Oh well, that's embarassing. I wrote the same amount of bytes as another answer and that one has got five downvotes. Oops.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I don't know C, but this fails on words with spaces [TIO](https://tio.run/##JctBCsMgEIXhfU8xpBvFtNBtxnoXa9J0FhnFMQRScnYr6erB//hCSrc5hFqvtKSYi6UoJU9@cRfiAoTnLJ5Y6a@UcRjaTTyD9MB4hkDsHOM7ZoUEFvgutE9KI5AxDZlnK@urOUX9Q5sOOjz@Mq7FWsGj1i3mUWCj8gFJPkzyAw)

Comment: @tfbninja Fixed. cin isn't particularly fond of strings containing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 31 bytes

```julia
print(join(readline(),' ')*" ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctLCsMwDEXRrTwyiR1Ch11C9iFstVYQSrDlflbvBjq6nMHduwrdxzirmIf9EAuVKasYh7jOmOMyYYpjbF0Vb8le4PxxSPvXCzkKNRDaSYlBD@cKfnH9IhWqlC6vEEvas9jzOhhKzXEY334)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##JctBCsMwDAXRq3yyiQ2hyx4h9xC2WisIJdhy2p7eCXQ1vMVsXYWeYxxVzMO2i4XKlFWMQ1xmzHHCFMdYuyo@kr3A@euQ9q8XchRqILSDEoNezhV8cv0hFaqUbi8QS9qz2Ps@GErNsRs/Lg "Julia 0.6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## APL(NARS), 13 chars, 26 bytes

```
∊k,¨' '⍴⍨≢k←⍞
```

Input a line from standard input, and return a line, test:

```
∊k,¨' '⍴⍨≢k←⍞
hello there
h e l l o   t h e r e
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 10 bytes

```
{,/x,'" "}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlpHv0JHXUlBqfZ/mlJGalGqQmaxQnF@bqpCakVibkFOqkJJakWJjkJaUWZqXkqxntL//wA)

(Ignored the stdin constraint. Let me know if I should delete, am new to SE)

---

**EDIT**: i made a mistake WRT stdin functionality in k. thanks, @ngn, for the correction:

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 18 bytes

```
{1@,/(0:""),'" ";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqtrQQUdfw8BKSUlTR11JQcm69n9adOz/jNSiVIXMYoXi/NxUhdSKxNyCnFSFktSKEh2FtKLM1LyUYr3/AA)

---

## k4, 12 bytes

```
,/(0:0),'" "
```

which looks like:

```
 ,/(0:0),'" "
full-width text
"f u l l - w i d t h   t e x t "
```

Comment: Unless ngn/k is completely incapable of taking input any other way, you are not allowed to take input by adding it to your source code, even ignoring this challenge's explicit requirement to use STDIN.

Comment: @pppery there is no stdin functionality within k

Comment: [`0:""` reads from stdin](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqtrQQUdfw8BKSUlTR11JQcm69n9adOz/jNSiVIXMYoXi/NxUhdSKxNyCnFSFktSKEh2FtKLM1LyUYr3/AA)

Comment: @ngn TIL... i will update. thanks!

Comment: by the way, it's `0:\`` in k7 (shakti), i'll add that as an alternative next time i update ngn/k

Comment: @ngn thank you for the info. it's really appreciated. question: is `0:""` ngn/k-compatible only? the above breaks in k4 (i do most of my work in k4 and adapt to ngn/k as necessary to provide a TIO link).

Comment: it was in k6 before it got abandoned. the one-page summary at kparc had this in it: `0:""0:"prompt" /readline writeline` (well, it's not exactly the same. i assumed empty filename means stdin.)

Comment: @ngn got back to this today. in k4 `0:0` will read (`0:`) from console which is handle `0`. thanks for showing me this, i hadn't encountered stdin in q/k before!

Answer (score 2):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w), 4 bytes

```
 "+M
```

### Explanation

```
   M % Foreach the input list:
  +  % Join the current item with ...
 "   % ... A space character
```

Answer (score 2):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), <s>50</s> <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```
2x1v1x1f0a0x1x2f1r3x1v1e1o0m8a4m1o2f0x2f
```

Works for any null-terminated input string.

*Saved 8 bytes by condensing the code into 2 functions instead of 3!*

[Try it online!](https://sporeball.dev/naz/?code=2x1v1x1f0a0x1x2f1r3x1v1e1o0m8a4m1o2f0x2f&input=Full%2520width%2520text&n=true)

**Explanation** (with `0x` instructions removed)

```
2x1v                     # Set variable 1 equal to 0
1x1f0a                   # Function 1
                         # Add 0 to the register
1x2f1r3x1v1e             # Function 2
                         # Read a byte of input
                         # Goto function 1 if it equals variable 1
            1o0m8a4m1o2f # Otherwise, output it, output a space,
                         # then call function 2
2f                       # Call function 2
```

The only way for a naz program to know when to stop reading its input is to give it a special case to check for; here we use a null byte, since a value of 0 can be stored immediately.

Answer (score 2):

## [Grok](https://github.com/AMiller42/Grok-Language), 13 bytes

```
:lYW!j
q}W Ih
```

I just finished my first Esolang and decided to submit a Code-golf answer with it to show it off. It's inspired by Befunge, ><>, and the Vim editor. More information on it is in the GitHub repository.

Comment: This looks really cool! I've got a [bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadline/19367#19367) for interesting new languages, and I think this would count as one. If you want I can give this a +100 bounty, or if you want to post another answer that shows off more language features I could award it to that one

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Thanks! I'm glad you like it! I think I'll try and find another challenge so I can show off the features more, especially the register.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I think [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223333/101522) answer would be a good one for the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

## [CLC-INTERCAL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CLC-INTERCAL), 108 bytes.

```
DO;1<-#1DO;1SUB#1<-#117DO;2<-#1DOCOMEFROM#9DOWRITEIN;2(1)DO:1<-;2SUB#1DDOCOMEFROM':1~:1'~#1(9)DOREADOUT;2+;1
```

[Copy and paste to try it online!](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb)

### How it works

````
DONOTE ;1 has " "
DONOTE ;2 shall accept a character
DO;1<-#1
DO;1SUB#1<-#117
DO;2<-#1

DOCOMEFROM#9
  DOWRITEIN;2
  DONOTE if EOF, then :1 will be #0
  DONOTE otherwise it's at least #65536
  (1)DO:1<-;2SUB#1
  DONOTE error exit here
  D
  DONOTE come here if not EOF
  DOCOMEFROM':1~:1'~#1
(9)DOREADOUT;2+;1
```
````

Answer (score 1):

### [Minkolang 0.15](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang) - 9 bytes

```
od?.O" "O
```

[Try it here!](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=od%3F%2EO%22%20%22O&input=Full%20width%20text%20is%20text%20that%20has%20a%20space%20after%20every%20character%2C%20including%20the%20last%20one%2E)

#### Explanation

```
o            Take character from input
 d           Duplicate top of stack
  ?.         Pop top of stack and jump over the . if truthy, stop otherwise
    O        Output input char
     " "O    Output a space
```

Minkolang's codebox is toroidal, hence there is no need to put an explicit loop in it.

Answer (score 1):

### Convex, 3 bytes

Convex is a new language that I am developing that is heavily based on CJam and Golfscript. The interpreter and IDE can be found [here](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex). Input is an integer into the command line arguments. Indexes are one-based. Uses the CP-1252 encoding.

```
S*S
```

Explanation:

```
     # Implied input
S*   # Join by spaces
  S  # Add a space at the end
     # Implied output
```

Additionally, [@DonMuesli's CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75997/36670) without the `l` (so `Sf+`) will also work for 3 bytes.

Comment: Update this post later?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy oh, my bad, I forgot, will do now.

Answer (score 1):

### sed, 8 bytes

```
s/./& /g
```

When running this from the shell you should quote it of course e.g.

```
echo Full Width Text | sed 's/./& /g' | od -c
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 39 bytes

```python
print("".join([x+" "for x in input()]))
```

Comment: You could just join with a `" "` rather than insert it with the comprehension.  Then all you need to worry about is the trailing space at the end.  `print(" ".join(input())+" ")` gets you down to 28 bytes

Comment: This is now exact duplicate of [Raffi](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51672/raffi)'s [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76034), which reached this format 1 day 01:30:09 hour earlier.

Comment: @manatwork I see. Should I change my old answer back or something? Thanks for telling!

Comment: Just improve it more. ;) In meantime I would revert to the previous version – it demonstrates the usage of a very popular Python feature, which has better chances for positive votes than a duplicate.

Comment: @manatwork Very good point! Reverted it. Back to 39 bytes :D

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 41 bytes

```rb
puts gets.chomp.chars.map{|e|e+" "}.join
```

`chomp` eats trailing newlines.

Comment: There is no requirement to output the whole result at once. If you output it piece-by-piece, you can spare the `.join` call. Even more, if you not need to return the pieces from the code block, then you can spare the `.map` call too, as `.chars` also accepts code block. And there is no restriction against adding a space after the trailing newline too, if there is one. `gets.chars{|e|$><<e+" "}`

Answer (score 1):

## [SMBF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Self-modifying_Brainfuck), 9 bytes

Note the trailing space. Uses the space in the code rather than creating a 32 in a cell.

```
,[.<.>,]
```

The tryitonline.net interpreter appears to have a bug and loop indefinitely with this, so it only works in [my Python interpreter](https://ideone.com/L2byRe). Changing the SMBF source code (currently on line 171) inside the Python code is required.

Answer (score 1):

## Go, <s>154</s> 120 bytes

```
package main
import(
."fmt"
."os"
."strings")
func main(){s:=Join(Args[1:], " ")
for _,c:=range s{Print(string(c)," ")}}
```

Saved a few bytes with command line args.

Answer (score 1):

## Vitsy, 10 bytes

```
zl\[O' 'O]

z          Grab all string input.
 l\[     ] Do the stuff in the brackets length of the stack times.
    O   O  Output as character.
     ' '   Push literal space.
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=emxcW08nICdPXQ&input=&args=RnVsbCB3aWR0aCB0ZXh0IGlzIHRleHQgdGhhdCBoYXMgYSBzcGFjZSBhZnRlciBldmVyeSBjaGFyYWN0ZXIsIGluY2x1ZGluZyB0aGUgbGFzdCBvbmUuIEZvciBpbnN0YW5jZSwgdGhlIGZpcnN0IHNlbnRlbmNlIG9mIHRoaXMgcXVlc3Rpb24gYmVjb21lczo)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 35 bytes

```
Console.readLine.map(_+" ")mkString
```

Example:

```
scala> Console.readLine.map(_+" ")mkString
res1: String = "H e l l o   S c a l a ! "
```

PS. A function would be slightly shorter (32 bytes):

```
(s:String)=>s.map(_+" ")mkString
```

Answer (score 1):

## LiveScript, 17.

```
->"#{it/''*' '} "
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 11 bytes

```
{,/' ',¨⍵}
```

catenate ' ' with each in omega (argument), then join (reduce-catenate, `,/`)

Comment: You don't need the `⍨` anymore. 10 bytes: `{,/⍵,¨' '}`

Comment: @Zacharý "anymore"?

Comment: I thought you originally had it to save bytes, guess I was wrong. Either way, you don't need `⍨`.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 42 bytes

```
Print@@(#<>" "&)/@Characters@InputString[]
```

Pretty self-explanatory. `InputString` takes a line from STDIN, `Characters` converts it to a list of characters, `(#<>" "&)/@` produces a new string with spaces after those characters, and `Print` prints the result.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, <s>11</s> 10 + 1 flags = 11 bytes

really, the same as the Perl 6 one, but the sed syntax changed.

```
s/./$& /g
```

example:

```
perl -pe "s/./$& /g" <<< abc
```

<s>old:</s>

```
perl -pne "s/(.)/\1 /g" <<< abc
```

Comment: Can you save a byte by using `s/./$& /gp`?

Comment: The `-n` flag is unnecessary, isn't it?

Comment: @Doorknob is indeed correct, you can omit `-p`, also, how flexible is the output format? If a leading space is acceptable `s// /g` works too!

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to have a leading space :). Thanks @Doorknob

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 87 bytes

```
@set/pt=&set w=
:l
@if not "%t%"=="" set w=%w%%t:~,1% &set t=%t:~1%&goto l
@echo(%w%
```

Conveniently taking input from STDIN is the same length as taking it from program arguments (`set t=%*`). The space between the `%` and `&` on the third line is significant, of course. The `(` after the `echo` simply prevents it from erroring out if the input is empty.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <strike>31</strike> 28

```python
print(' '.join(input())+' ')
```

I know i'm late on this one, and definitely not a winner, but thought i'd try it out.

**Edit:** Switched to python 3. Thanks to *CatsAreFluffy* for saving 3 bytes!

Comment: You can cut one byte by removing the space after `print`.

Comment: Or just switch to Python 3 (and cut 3 bytes): `print(' '.join(input)+' ')`. `raw_input` is more expensive than parens with `print`.

Answer (score 1):

## Grond, <strike>22</strike> 21 chars

```
a(p().sp('').jn(' '))
```

Edit: removed semicolon
compiler in js below

```js
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
  return this.split("").reverse().join("");
}
function compile(source){
var wc = source; // wc stands for working copy 
var lastWC;
while (true) {
  lastWC = wc;
  wc = wc.reverse();
  wc = wc.replace(/\(a(?!\w)/, "(trela"); //alert ,a
  wc = wc.replace(/\(f(?!\w)/, "(rof"); // for, f
  wc = wc.replace(/\(w(?!\w)/, "(elihw"); //while,w
  wc = wc.replace(/\(p(?!\w)/, "(tpmorp"); //prompt,p
  wc = wc.replace(/\(vr\./, "(esrever."); //reverse, rv
  wc = wc.replace(/\(tm\./, "(chtam."); // match, mt
  wc = wc.replace(/\(nj\./, "(nioj."); //join, .jn
  wc = wc.replace(/\(pr\./, "(ecalper."); //replace, .rp
  wc = wc.replace(/\(ls\./, "(.ecils"); //slice, sl
  wc = wc.replace(/\(lt\./, "(esaCrewoLot."); //toLowerCase, tl
  wc = wc.replace(/\(ut\./, "(esaCreppUot."); //toUpperCase, tu
    wc = wc.replace(/\(ps\./, "(tilps."); //split, sp
  wc = wc.reverse();
  wc = wc.replace(/\.l(?!\w)/, ".length"); // .length, .l
  if (lastWC === wc)
    break;
}

// quine builtin commented out because it messes things up TODO: Fix it. 
wc = " String.prototype.la=function(h){var x=this.split(''); x[h] = x[h].toLowerCase(); return x.join('');};String.prototype.ca=function(h){var x=this.split(''); x[h] = x[h].toUpperCase(); return x.join('');};String.prototype.reverse=function(){return this.split('').reverse().join('');}; \n var h = ['hello, world', 'Hello, World', 'Hello, World!', 'hello, world!', 'hello world', 'hello world!', 'Hello World', 'Hello World!', 'Hello, world.', 'Hello, World.' ,'hello world.' , 'Hello World.']; /* var q ='" + source + "';*/ " + wc;

return wc;
  }
eval(compile("a(p().sp('').jn(' '));"));//source
```

Grond on github: https://github.com/epicTCK/Grond

Answer (score 1):

### [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```nim
for c in stdin.readAll:stdout.write c&' '
```

I sure hope there's a better way, but `readChar` didn't seem to help...

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/qRQsJx)

Answer (score 1):

## Reng v.1.2, 15 bytes

[Try it out here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) The input is given as `"input"`.

```
ai p|$raoWo?!|~
```

`a` is a one-way mirror from the left. `ai p|` gets all input, `$` drops the residual `-1` not found input, `r` reverses the stack, and `aoWo?!|~` is an output loop. `W` pushes 32, the space, and outputs it after outputting the character. `?!` breaks out if not true, and `~` ends the program.

Answer (score 1):

## [RETURN](https://github.com/molarmanful/RETURN), 10 bytes

```
`""¨{' °},
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://molarmanful.github.io/RETURN/)</kbd>

Takes input from STDIN. It's just take STDIN, split along chars, join with space, output.

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 7 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=cDRpKmxpBQ&input=SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ)

```
p4i*li♣
p4       interweave
  i      the input
   *li♣  with a string of spaces with = length to the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## , 5 chars / 7 bytes

```
ᴉü⬭+⬭
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=false&input=asdf&code=%E1%B4%89%C3%BC%E2%AC%AD%2B%E2%AC%AD)</kbd>

Short and sweet. Get input split along chars and join with space.

Comment: This doesn't produce a trailing space.

Comment: I think I fixed it, but I'm on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 34 bytes

```
#(apply str(mapcat(fn[x][x" "])%))
```

Clojure is amazingly fun to work with but annoying to golf.  Usually there's a really nice idiomatic solution to these challenges that isn't that many identifiers, but it's massive thanks to things like the identity function being `identity` (not fully golfed in these forms):

```
(defn fw [s] (apply str (interleave s (repeat " "))))
```

or

```
(defn fw [s] (apply str (mapcat (juxt identity (constantly " ")) s)))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 31 Bytes

**Saved 1 byte thanks to @LeakyNun**

A simple chained substitution, replace each character by itself and a space.

```lua
s=(...):gsub(".","%1 ")print(s)
```

An other solution with the same byte count:

```lua
print((...):gsub(".","%1 "),'')
```

Comment: @manatwork I don't see how I did to miss this! Print automatically had a tab between each of it's parameters, totally forgot that point. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Can you change `arg[1]` to `...`?

Answer (score 1):

## O 1.2, 6 bytes

```
I' ]^o
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ java xyz.jadonfowler.o.O <(echo "I' ]^o") <<< 'Full width text.'
F u l l   w i d t h   t e x t .
```

This could be 5 characters in O 2 as `IT]^o`, but sadly it not seems to fully support the `^` command yet.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 8 bytes

```
,@,.&' '
```

`,.` is the stitch command, and `' ' , 'string'` creates a table with a space following each character. `,` takes these items out of the table when used as a monad, and `@` composes this function with our other function. Use:

```
   fullWidth =: ,@,.&' '
   fullWidth 'this text is full width!'
   fullWidth 'this text is full width!'
t h i s   t e x t   i s   f u l l   w i d t h !
```

Great thanks to Zgarb who helped me make this answer.

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 32 bytes

```ps
-join([char[]]$args[0]|%{"$_ "})
```

---

**Explanation**

Take in the input to the function and convert it to a char array. Add one space to each character and rejoin. Nothing really fancy here.

Comment: Save a couple bytes by just joining it directly and encapsulating in a script block in a string -- `"$([char[]]$args[0]-join' ') "`

Answer (score 1):

### [Prelude](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude), 11 bytes

```
?(!8^+^+!?)
```

This needs a spec-compliant interpreter which reads and writes character codes (instead of integers).

The program is fairly simple.

```
?(...?)
```

This sets up a `while(read() != EOF)` loop. Then we simply have:

```
!   Print input character.
8   Push 8.
^+  Duplicate, add. Gives 16.
^+  Duplicate, add. Gives 32.
!   Print space.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 40 bytes

```
(map()(lambda(x)(format t"~C "x))(read))
```

I was very surprised that `format` couldn't do this by itself: it can only iterate over lists, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 5 bytes

```
_.sMq
```

The special variable `q` reads a line of stdin. We `M`ap to it the lambda function `_.s`, which concatenates a space to each character. By default, the resulting list is concatenated and autoprinted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ouroboros](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Ouroboros), 11 bytes

```
i.0<5*(o32o
```

Ouroboros is an esolang in which every line of code represents a snake eating its tail. It draws a fair amount of inspiration from 2D languages like Befunge and ><>.

The `i` command reads a character, or `-1` for EOF. We duplicate this, check if it's less than `0`, and multiply the resulting `1` (true) or `0` (false) by `5`.

- If we have reached EOF, the top of the stack is now `5`. The `(` command tells the snake to eat that many characters of its tail. This results in swallowing the execution pointer (currently on `(`, the fifth-last character), which terminates the program.
- Otherwise, `0` characters are eaten, and execution continues. We have a copy of the input ASCII code on the stack, which we output via `o`; then output a space (ASCII 32) and loop back to the beginning.

#### Try it out

```js
// Define Stack class
function Stack() {
  this.stack = [];
  this.length = 0;
}
Stack.prototype.push = function(item) {
  this.stack.push(item);
  this.length++;
}
Stack.prototype.pop = function() {
  var result = 0;
  if (this.length > 0) {
    result = this.stack.pop();
    this.length--;
  }
  return result;
}
Stack.prototype.top = function() {
  var result = 0;
  if (this.length > 0) {
    result = this.stack[this.length - 1];
  }
  return result;
}
Stack.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "" + this.stack;
}

// Define Snake class
function Snake(code) {
  this.code = code;
  this.length = this.code.length;
  this.ip = 0;
  this.ownStack = new Stack();
  this.currStack = this.ownStack;
  this.alive = true;
  this.wait = 0;
  this.partialString = this.partialNumber = null;
}
Snake.prototype.step = function() {
  if (!this.alive) {
    return null;
  }
  if (this.wait > 0) {
    this.wait--;
    return null;
  }
  var instruction = this.code.charAt(this.ip);
  var output = null;
  console.log("Executing instruction " + instruction);
  if (this.partialString !== null) {
    // We're in the middle of a double-quoted string
    if (instruction == '"') {
      // Close the string and push its character codes in reverse order
      for (var i = this.partialString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.currStack.push(this.partialString.charCodeAt(i));
      }
      this.partialString = null;
    } else {
      this.partialString += instruction;
    }
  } else if (instruction == '"') {
    this.partialString = "";
  } else if ("0" <= instruction && instruction <= "9") {
    if (this.partialNumber !== null) {
      this.partialNumber = this.partialNumber + instruction;  // NB: concatenation!
    } else {
      this.partialNumber = instruction;
    }
    next = this.code.charAt((this.ip + 1) % this.length);
    if (next < "0" || "9" < next) {
      // Next instruction is non-numeric, so end number and push it
      this.currStack.push(+this.partialNumber);
      this.partialNumber = null;
    }
  } else if ("a" <= instruction && instruction <= "f") {
    // a-f push numbers 10 through 15
    var value = instruction.charCodeAt(0) - 87;
    this.currStack.push(value);
  } else if (instruction == "$") {
    // Toggle the current stack
    if (this.currStack === this.ownStack) {
      this.currStack = this.program.sharedStack;
    } else {
      this.currStack = this.ownStack;
    }
  } else if (instruction == "s") {
    this.currStack = this.ownStack;
  } else if (instruction == "S") {
    this.currStack = this.program.sharedStack;
  } else if (instruction == "l") {
    this.currStack.push(this.ownStack.length);
  } else if (instruction == "L") {
    this.currStack.push(this.program.sharedStack.length);
  } else if (instruction == ".") {
    var item = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(item);
    this.currStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "m") {
    var item = this.ownStack.pop();
    this.program.sharedStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "M") {
    var item = this.program.sharedStack.pop();
    this.ownStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "y") {
    var item = this.ownStack.top();
    this.program.sharedStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "Y") {
    var item = this.program.sharedStack.top();
    this.ownStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "\\") {
    var top = this.currStack.pop();
    var next = this.currStack.pop()
    this.currStack.push(top);
    this.currStack.push(next);
  } else if (instruction == "@") {
    var c = this.currStack.pop();
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(c);
    this.currStack.push(a);
    this.currStack.push(b);
  } else if (instruction == ";") {
    this.currStack.pop();
  } else if (instruction == "+") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a + b);
  } else if (instruction == "-") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a - b);
  } else if (instruction == "*") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a * b);
  } else if (instruction == "/") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a / b);
  } else if (instruction == "%") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a % b);
  } else if (instruction == "_") {
    this.currStack.push(-this.currStack.pop());
  } else if (instruction == "I") {
    var value = this.currStack.pop();
    if (value < 0) {
      this.currStack.push(Math.ceil(value));
    } else {
      this.currStack.push(Math.floor(value));
    }
  } else if (instruction == ">") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(+(a > b));
  } else if (instruction == "<") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(+(a < b));
  } else if (instruction == "=") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(+(a == b));
  } else if (instruction == "!") {
    this.currStack.push(+ !this.currStack.pop());
  } else if (instruction == "?") {
    this.currStack.push(Math.random());
  } else if (instruction == "n") {
    output = "" + this.currStack.pop();
  } else if (instruction == "o") {
    output = String.fromCharCode(this.currStack.pop());
  } else if (instruction == "r") {
    var input = this.program.io.getNumber();
    this.currStack.push(input);
  } else if (instruction == "i") {
    var input = this.program.io.getChar();
    this.currStack.push(input);
  } else if (instruction == "(") {
    this.length -= Math.floor(this.currStack.pop());
    this.length = Math.max(this.length, 0);
  } else if (instruction == ")") {
    this.length += Math.floor(this.currStack.pop());
    this.length = Math.min(this.length, this.code.length);
  } else if (instruction == "w") {
    this.wait = this.currStack.pop();
  }
  // Any unrecognized character is a no-op
  if (this.ip >= this.length) {
    // We've swallowed the IP, so this snake dies
    this.alive = false;
    this.program.snakesLiving--;
  } else {
    // Increment IP and loop if appropriate
    this.ip = (this.ip + 1) % this.length;
  }
  return output;
}
Snake.prototype.getHighlightedCode = function() {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < this.code.length; i++) {
    if (i == this.length) {
      result += '<span class="swallowedCode">';
    }
    if (i == this.ip) {
      if (this.wait > 0) {
        result += '<span class="nextActiveToken">';
      } else {
        result += '<span class="activeToken">';
      }
      result += escapeEntities(this.code.charAt(i)) + '</span>';
    } else {
      result += escapeEntities(this.code.charAt(i));
    }
  }
  if (this.length < this.code.length) {
    result += '</span>';
  }
  return result;
}

// Define Program class
function Program(source, speed, io) {
  this.sharedStack = new Stack();
  this.snakes = source.split(/\r?\n/).map(function(snakeCode) {
    var snake = new Snake(snakeCode);
    snake.program = this;
    snake.sharedStack = this.sharedStack;
    return snake;
  }.bind(this));
  this.snakesLiving = this.snakes.length;
  this.io = io;
  this.speed = speed || 10;
  this.halting = false;
}
Program.prototype.run = function() {
  this.step();
  if (this.snakesLiving) {
    this.timeout = window.setTimeout(this.run.bind(this), 1000 / this.speed);
  }
}
Program.prototype.step = function() {
   for (var s = 0; s < this.snakes.length; s++) {
    var output = this.snakes[s].step();
    if (output) {
      this.io.print(output);
    }
  }
  this.io.displaySource(this.snakes.map(function (snake) {
      return snake.getHighlightedCode();
    }).join("<br>"));
 }
Program.prototype.halt = function() {
  window.clearTimeout(this.timeout);
}

var ioFunctions = {
  print: function (item) {
    var stdout = document.getElementById('stdout');
    stdout.value += "" + item;
  },
  getChar: function () {
    if (inputData) {
      var inputChar = inputData[0];
      inputData = inputData.slice(1);
      result = inputChar.charCodeAt(0);
    } else {
      result = -1;
    }
    var stdinDisplay = document.getElementById('stdin-display');
    stdinDisplay.innerHTML = escapeEntities(inputData);
    return result;
  },
  getNumber: function () {
    while (inputData && (inputData[0] < "0" || "9" < inputData[0])) {
      inputData = inputData.slice(1);
    }
    if (inputData) {
      var inputNumber = inputData.match(/\d+/)[0];
      inputData = inputData.slice(inputNumber.length);
      result = +inputNumber;
    } else {
      result = -1;
    }
    var stdinDisplay = document.getElementById('stdin-display');
    stdinDisplay.innerHTML = escapeEntities(inputData);
    return result;
  },
  displaySource: function (formattedCode) {
    var sourceDisplay = document.getElementById('source-display');
    sourceDisplay.innerHTML = formattedCode;
  }
};
var program = null;
var inputData = null;
function showEditor() {
  var source = document.getElementById('source'),
    sourceDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('source-display-wrapper'),
    stdin = document.getElementById('stdin'),
    stdinDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('stdin-display-wrapper');
  
  source.style.display = "block";
  stdin.style.display = "block";
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.display = "none";
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.display = "none";
  
  source.focus();
}
function hideEditor() {
  var source = document.getElementById('source'),
    sourceDisplay = document.getElementById('source-display'),
    sourceDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('source-display-wrapper'),
    stdin = document.getElementById('stdin'),
    stdinDisplay = document.getElementById('stdin-display'),
    stdinDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('stdin-display-wrapper');
  
  source.style.display = "none";
  stdin.style.display = "none";
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.display = "block";
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.display = "block";
  
  var sourceHeight = getComputedStyle(source).height,
    stdinHeight = getComputedStyle(stdin).height;
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.minHeight = sourceHeight;
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.maxHeight = sourceHeight;
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.minHeight = stdinHeight;
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.maxHeight = stdinHeight;
  sourceDisplay.textContent = source.value;
  stdinDisplay.textContent = stdin.value;
}
function escapeEntities(input) {
  return input.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
function resetProgram() {
  var stdout = document.getElementById('stdout');
  stdout.value = null;
  if (program !== null) {
    program.halt();
  }
  program = null;
  inputData = null;
  showEditor();
}
function initProgram() {
  var source = document.getElementById('source'),
    stepsPerSecond = document.getElementById('steps-per-second'),
    stdin = document.getElementById('stdin');
  program = new Program(source.value, +stepsPerSecond.innerHTML, ioFunctions);
  hideEditor();
  inputData = stdin.value;
}
function runBtnClick() {
  if (program === null || program.snakesLiving == 0) {
    resetProgram();
    initProgram();
  } else {
    program.halt();
    var stepsPerSecond = document.getElementById('steps-per-second');
    program.speed = +stepsPerSecond.innerHTML;
  }
  program.run();
}
function stepBtnClick() {
  if (program === null) {
    initProgram();
  } else {
    program.halt();
  }
  program.step();
}
function sourceDisplayClick() {
  resetProgram();
}
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.so-box {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .3em .7em;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.1;
    border: 1px solid #c47b07;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background: #f88912;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset;
}
.control {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 6px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.option {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    float: left;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
input, textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea {
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 25px;
}
span[contenteditable] {
    padding: 2px 6px;
    background: #cc7801;
    color: #fff;
}
#stdout-container, #stdin-container {
    height: auto;
    padding: 6px 0;
}
#reset {
    float: right;
}
#source-display-wrapper , #stdin-display-wrapper{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#source-display , #stdin-display{
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 2px;
}
.activeToken {
    background: #f93;
}
.nextActiveToken {
    background: #bbb;
}
.swallowedCode{
    color: #999;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content:".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--
Designed and written 2015 by D. Loscutoff
Much of the HTML and CSS was taken from this Befunge interpreter by Ingo Bürk: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40331/16766
-->
<div class="container">
<textarea id="source" placeholder="Enter your program here" wrap="off">i.0<5*(o32o</textarea>
<div id="source-display-wrapper" onclick="sourceDisplayClick()"><div id="source-display"></div></div></div><div id="stdin-container" class="container">
<textarea id="stdin" placeholder="Input" wrap="off">Input text...</textarea>
<div id="stdin-display-wrapper" onclick="stdinDisplayClick()"><div id="stdin-display"></div></div></div><div id="controls-container" class="container clearfix"><input type="button" id="run" class="control so-box" value="Run" onclick="runBtnClick()" /><input type="button" id="pause" class="control so-box" value="Pause" onclick="program.halt()" /><input type="button" id="step" class="control so-box" value="Step" onclick="stepBtnClick()" /><input type="button" id="reset" class="control so-box" value="Reset" onclick="resetProgram()" /></div><div id="stdout-container" class="container"><textarea id="stdout" placeholder="Output" wrap="off" readonly></textarea></div><div id="options-container" class="container"><div class="option so-box">Steps per Second:
<span id="steps-per-second" contenteditable>20</span></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/), 5 bytes

```
+jdzd
```

[Test here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Bjdzd&input=Hello+World&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
 jdz    Join input with spaces
+   d   Concatenate space
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Silicon](http://github.com/m654z/Silicon), 6 bytes

```
iSæ%æ+
```

**Explanation:**

```
iSæ%æ+
i        Input
 S       Split the input
  æ      Push a space
   %     Join at spaces
    æ+   Append a space to the end of the string
         Implicit output
```

### <s>7 bytes</s>

```
iSæ²jæ+
```

Comment: Does Silicon have it's own encoding? Else, it would be 10 bytes in UTF-8 (and 7 chars).

Comment: @katenkyo [I think it has.](https://github.com/m654z/Silicon/blob/master/cp037.py)

Answer (score 1):

## [0815](https://esolangs.org/wiki/0815), 26 bytes

```
<:20:~>}: :!~$#:
:{~$>^: :
```

Answer (score 1):

### Tcl, 44 bytes

```
puts [regsub -all {(.)} [gets stdin] {\1 }]
```

Comment: You're byte count is wrong! It is 43!

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 35 bytes

```cs
s=>string.Join(" ",s.ToList())+" ";
```

C# lambda where the input and the output are `string`. You can try it on [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PMVa2M).

Comment: This requires a `using System.Linq` derivative, which should either be included or the language marked as LinqPad or similar.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 2.2, <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```
for c in i.characters{print(c,terminator:" ")}
```

Hey, at least it's shorter than Java...  Saved 2 chars by using a `for in` loop instead of a `forEach` closure.

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 41

```
puts [regsub -all (.) [gets stdin] \\1\ ]
```

on http://rextester.com/KCIB63188

Comment: Just noticed now, there was another Tcl answer!

Answer (score 1):

## C <s>55</s>, 49 bytes

```c
g(){c;while((c=getchar())!='\n')printf("%c ",c);}
```

Ungolfed version:

```c
void g()
{
  char c;
  while((c=getchar())!='\n')
  printf("%c ", c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-84 BASIC, 44 bytes

Pretty straightforward approach:

```
Input Str1
sub(Str1,1,1
For(A,2,length(Str1
Ans+" "+sub(Str1,A,1
End
Ans+"
```

The only size optimizations I could come up with were:

- leaving off closing quotes and parentheses at the end of lines
- using `Ans` instead of a string variable (the `Ans` token is 1 byte, `StrN` are 2, and assignment to `Ans` is implicit)
- printing the result by placing it on the last line of the program (no `Disp` command needed)

This program wouldn't work correctly for an empty input string, since it unconditionally stores the first character of `Str1` in `Ans`. (This is necessary because concatenation with an empty string raises an error!) Fortunately, the `Input` command doesn't accept an empty string in the first place.

The size calculation was informed by TI-Basic Developer's [token size charts](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/tokens).

Answer (score 1):

## [OIL](https://github.com/L3viathan/OIL), <s>52</s> 49 bytes noncompeting

*Note: The second line contains a space character.*

```
5

12
0
23
10
24
3
7
10
4
24
4
1
8
11
1
11
6
6
5
```

---

I explode the input string, then print each character and then a space.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 7 bytes

```
32DL:{'
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@29s5OJjVa3@//9/paD8/JKc1OJihZCi1FQlAA)

Works like so:

```
       \ Implicit: Input is on stack as charcodes
32D    \ Set the printing delimiter to a space
L:     \ Input length times do:
  {    \   Cyclically shift the stack left
   '   \   Print the last character (includes trailing space)
```

---

Alternatively, for the same byte count, one could have:

```
L:{32;"
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@@9jVW1sZK30//9/paD8/JKc1OJihZCi1FQlAA)

```
L:   ;   \ Length times do:
  {      \   Shift string left
   32    \   Insert char 32 (a space)
      "  \ Afterwards, print the whole string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

```
®+S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#JcvLCYAwEEXRVh5uFcuwASsYktEJhCiZiZ@mLMLGYsDV5SxufZ9@rrWbSow4gzeB8WUI@teEDEIKgu7kGLQYZ/DB@YYTyuSaB4TkYvEhre1gRFLDlnjsPg)

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 57 bytes

```lua
t=""io.read():gsub(".",function(c)t=t..c.." "end)print(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC 3, 44 bytes

```
INPUT A$FOR I=0TO LEN(A$)-1?A$[I]+" ";
NEXT
```

This doesn't leave a new line after the output, so from direct you might get

```
?HELLO
H E L L O OK
```

but hopefully it's not an issue.

Comment: You can make the loop shorter by doing: `WHILE""<A$?SHIFT(A$);" ";:WEND`

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 52 bytes

Manual, straightforward approach, without using Linq.

```cs
s=>{var r="";foreach(var c in s)r+=c+" ";return r;};
```

Anonymous method which gets every character from the string and adds a space after each one.

Full program:

```cs
using System;

namespace FullWidthText
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<string, string> f =
            s =>
            {
                var r = "";
                foreach (var c in s)
                    r += c + " ";
                return r;
            };

            Console.WriteLine(f("Full width text is text that has a space after every character, including the last one."));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Vim, <s>12</s> 10 keystrokes

```
:s/./& /g<CR>
```

1 byte longer:

```
qqa <Esc>l@qq@q
```

-2 bytes thanks to @KritixiLithos

Comment: You don't need to delete the last space and `:s/./\0 /g<CR>$x` can become just `:s/./& /g<CR>` at 10 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb+, 12 bytes

**Solution:**

```
raze{x,'" "}
```

**Example:**

```
q)raze{x,'" "}"Hello World!"
"H e l l o   W o r l d ! "
```

**Explanation:**

```
,'   / join (,) each left ("H", "e", "l"...) with each right (" ")
raze / reduce list
```

**Notes:**

Would be 9 bytes doing it more directly rather than as a lambda function:

```
q)raze"Hello World!",'" "
"H e l l o   W o r l d ! "
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 19 bytes

```
s=>[...s,,].join` `
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 46 bytes

```
{({}<>)<>}<>{({}<>)((((()()()()){}){}){})<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUtbDsIwDLuKP1eJcYJpn9wjdNkaURXUZjxU7eyhsNmWnUj2NZOkfo50M6td3YbRDWPz4@5@cDtd3Q79G2aXNUa8ZNIA5bdCyp4aSBGogFAe5Bk0K2fwk/MHPlAm3/4TJPm4TpKWtmBEKop74rP1/gs)

Explanation:

```
#Reverse the whole stack
{({}<>)<>}<>

#Reverse the whole stack, 
{({}<>)

    #Pushing 32 between each character
    ((((()()()()){}){}){})<>}<>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 bytes

Requires `⎕ML←0` which used to be standard

```apl
,⍪,∊
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qr8@jtgkG/9OApM6j3lU6jzq6/v9PU1B3K83JKc9MKclQKEmtKFEHAA)

`,` ravel (flatten)

`⍪` the columnified argument

`,` followed by

`∊` the prototypes (one space per character)

Comment: Can you explain why this needs to be encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: @Zacharý Does it? Is `⎕AVU` no good?

Comment: Clarification: Why this is 12 bytes and not 4?

Comment: @Zacharý Ah, simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3,  <del>95 93 92 80 32 26</del>  30 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to @caird coinheringaahing

Saved bunch of bytes from @DJMcMayhem + My idea

```
print(' '.join(input())+' ')
```

Takes input, splits it, then prints a join with spaces

This is my first time golfing.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You can remove a byte by removing the space after the `:` as well as taking a look at [these](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) tips for Python golfing

Comment: You could get this down to a one-liner: `print(''.join(i+' 'for i in input())`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem, made it even shorter :)

Comment: Does this print a space after the last character? And do you need the `list()` part?

Comment: oh, one second.

Answer (score 1):

## Brainfuck, 23 <s>24</s> <s>25</s> Bytes

#### 1 Byte thanks to ovs

```
-[-[-<]>>+<]>-<+[,.>.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fNxoIbWLt7LSBhK6NdrSOnp2eTez//275@U6JRQA)

This code makes use of most interpreters wrapping to 255 if the number is negative.

## Previous solution:

```
++++[>++++++++<-]+[,.>.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwii7bShwEY3VjtaR89Ozyb2/3@3/HynxCIA)

### Explanation:

```
++++[>++++++++<-]   |Leaves the second cell with the number 32, the ASCII Code for a space.
+[,.>.<]            |Simple loop, gets the input, outputs it and adds a space.
```

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fTjcaCG1i7ey0gYSujXa0jp6dnk3s//9u@flOiUUA). The initialization part is taken from [this page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants)

Comment: Cool, very nice. I have problems understanding your program though. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: The code makes use of the fact that most brainfuck implementations use wrapping 8-bit cells. If you decrement a cell that is zero, you get to `255`. [Here is a simple example](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fV@//fwA).

Comment: The `,` should be at the end of the loop, otherwise you print an extra nul byte. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fNxoIbWLt7LSBhK6NTrSenZ6NTuz//275@U6JRQA)

Comment: [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fNxoIbWLt7LRtYrWjdfTsdPWArP//3fLznRKLAA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>4</s> 3 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
 ］∑
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjVCJTIwJXVGRjNEJXUyMjEx,i=SGVsbG8lMkMlMjBXb3JsZCUyMQ__)

Explanation:

```
   Push input to stack (implicit)
   For each character in the input: (implicit)
   Push the character to the stack (implicit)
   Push " " to the stack
］ Collapse results from loop into an array
∑  Join the array into a single string
   Print the ToS (implicit)
```

*-1 byte thanks to [dzaima](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59183/dzaima)!*

Comment: You can remove the leading `｛` as it can be implicit for 3 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## k, 10 bytes

```
{,/x,'" "}
```

#### Explanation

`{..}` is the lambda syntax

`x,'""` takes the first argument x, and applies the join operator `,` to every character, creating an array of "l " pairs

`,/` folds the array with the join operator

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 7 bytes

```
iEH}` }
```

Courtesy of JoKing, who golfed this to the max!!! JoKing combined the loops into one simple loop, also avoided the mistake I made, I added 2 spaces rather than one.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcvLCYBADEXRVl4BYheKZRjGaAJhlEn8Lax9FFxdzuIuq83qUqt2wzPiqbXfzXDqFILgK6D@N4QCQg6Cb5QYNAcX8MHlRhIqlD430JxsnzQv38Ew8sCauX0B)

**Slightly newer of My original golfed, 23 bytes**

```
Ti:0)?t~l&T` }}&M:&?trH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/PyTTykDTvqQuRy0kQaG2Vs3XSs2@pMjj/38PTx0FD/9wBccgV4VI/1AA)

**Old version, 28 bytes**

```
Ti:0)?t~l&T"  "}}}&M:&0)?trH
```

This can probably be golfed futher, but code breakdown below!

```
Ti:0)?t~l&T"  "}}}&M:&0)?trH

Ti:0)?t~                    //gets every char from input, and pushes them to the stack
          T"  "}}}          //push 2 spaces after every char, push to the bottom of the stack for later
        l&T       &M:&0)?t  //push original length and store, every loop decrement and if it is greater than zero, repeat
                          rH//reverse stack and output the whole stack as characters
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/PyTTykDTvqQuRy1ESUFBqba2Vs3XSg0kVOTx/7@Hp46Ch3@4gmOQq0KkfygA)

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcvLCYBADEXRVl4BYheKZRjGaAJhlEn8Lax9FFxdzuIuq83qUqt2wzPiqbXfzXDqFILgK6D@N4QCQg6Cb5QYNAcX8MHlRhIqlD430JxsnzQv38Ew8sCauX0B). Mostly because you can combine all the loops into one loop over the input

Comment: @JoKing Wow, that is really smart using the E function! Also I just realized that it only needs one space, and that I forgot to add spaces after the last characters, sorry!

Comment: @JoKing Almost managed 6 bytes, but it prints entirely backwards...  iEH@`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 14 bytes

```perl6
put get.comb,$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcs9DsIwEEThq0xBGaXkCNxj2QyxpcWx7DE/pzeRqJ6@4lW2uM5Zh7BTqx/P@3KZ8zYi8M6bEsSPkPu/SiYk6zD0ak7YQ2zgi@0LT9bMTy/IxWNsueznQYR14Shcfw)

Prints a trailing newline.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
put             # print to stdout
    get.comb    # the list of characters in the input, 
            ,$  # And an empty string
put             # Implicitly separated by spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 24 bytes

```powershell
"$args"-replace'.','$0 '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0klsSi9WEm3KLUgJzE5VV1PXUddxUBB/f///26lOTkK5ZkpJRkKJakVJXoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 21 bytes

```sh
echo ${(s::)$(<&0)}\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/NTkjX0GlWqPYykpTRcNGzUCzNkbh/38VDefEgpLSolSF4pKUzDxNHQWwioKczBKF/DyF5IzEosTkktSiYh0FkAl6AA)

`$(capture)`, `${(s::)plit}`, `echo`. The last `"\ "` is needed for the trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 6 bytes

```
"#@~,,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XUnao09H5/9@tNCdHoTwzpSRDoSS1okQPAA)

The Befunge-98 answer is pretty long, so here is a shorter one. Basically the same answer as [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76088/88939) Befunge-93 answer by Sp3000, but ends up being half as long, thanks to Befunge-98s ~ reflecting on EOF.

One thing that bugged me is, that when you run it on multi line input, every line but the first will be indented (since the linebreak will be followed by a space as well), so here is a version (11 bytes), that doesn't have that problem.

```
"#@~:,a-!j,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XUnaos9JJ1FXM0vn/3600J0ehPDOlJEOhJLWiRI/LN78oVSENVdQeAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-rs`, 3 bytes

```
( '
```

Shifts the input putting a space after each character, reverses the stack via the `-rs` flag and then implicitly outputs the stack.

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <s>17</s> 8 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to @mazzy!

```
"$args "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9X0klsSi9WEHpfy0Xl0oxUEjJAyibr6MQnl@Uk6KoxKUGVOhQrKCgrFBckJNYUpKZl/4fAA)

There are already a couple of PowerShell answers to this question, but I thought I'd throw mine into the mix. It takes splatter input from a command line argument. It also assumes that `$ofs` is equal to one space, which it is by default.

Comment: Great! The codegolf allow you to use an char array instead of a string. Therefore, [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##NctBCoAgEEbhvaf4maRbBN2hEwxiGojKjBQRnd3ctH18r5bLi0afUrc7FjydLEtQUH@NsToSbTVxa0cOcCWfXpqiFbjIAhbhm8w83lWBCfrb/gE "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy finally, a competitive PowerShell answer ;)  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `Ṫ`, <s><sup>3</sup></s> 2 bytes

```
Ṅð
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=%E1%B9%AA&code=%E1%B9%84%C3%B0&inputs=Hello%2C%20World!&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
     # Implicit input
Ṅ    # Insert ' ' between each character
  ð  # Push ' '
     # 'Ṫ' flag - sum entire stack and print
```

---

### If the final space wasn't necessary:

### Vyxal `S`, 0 bytes

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=S&code=&inputs=Hello%2C%20World!&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
  # Implicit input
  # 'S' flag - Print top of stack joined by spaces
```

Comment: `ð*` with `s` also works for 2 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore C64 BASIC, 39 Tokenised BASIC bytes, 42 PETSCII characters with keyword abbreviations

```
0INPUTA$:FORI=1TOLEN(A$):?MID$(A$,I,1)" ";:NEXT
```

On running this listing, the interpreter will expect an input of strings which when the return key is pressed, will store the text entered into the variable `A$`. It will then iterate over each position of the string to its length and `PRINT` it, proceeded by a white space, and then will continue at the next cursor position until the final character of the string is printed (this will be followed by a space too).

Some notes: A Commodore C64 screen is 40 characters wide by default, and the maximum number of characters that may be stored in a string is 255, however, when using `INPUT` the interpreter will only accept a total entry of 77 characters without some trickery (80 characters if you delete the ? prompt, enter 80 characters and then cursor up two lines and press the RETURN key).

See screenshot for this in action.

[image: Commodore C64 Full Width Text CodeGolf challenge]

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 90 bytes

This is a full `program` suitable for a processor supporting “Standard Pascal” and/or “Extended Pascal” as defined by ISO standards 7185 and 10206 respectively.
As per specification it takes *a line* (not many lines).
Note, calling `EOLn(input)` causes an error if `EOF(input)` is `true` prior invocation of `EOLn`.
Hence it must be guaranteed that input contains at least an end‑of‑line marker.

```pascal
program p(input,output);begin while not EOLn do begin write(input↑,' ');get(input)end end.
```

We can add **−10 bytes** if it is guaranteed that `input` is a non‑empty line:

```pascal
program p(input,output);begin repeat write(input↑,' ');get(input)until EOLn end.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 5 bytes

```
,/2$'
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxVUGFrwyAQ/e6veITCNkgjDEZp8r1/ohQq5kykNnZq2oSx/faddl+G6L3ne3enZ9pavm9ehEjt1+a4/oTWAFi6s790r2ejrOuWbu3C2+mbPcfqMDuHh+3TiERLgo3PmEaVMKoIhXhTmqBMogC6U1ihRxWUZl7DTtrNvZ0GziA4FRP8RE0lgOqAGY4X8IBFDy7IOIGw8Am+i/941lVBOWZN8Y64cdTsytwUf2BMuBe0MtYlIxTfU69L/Ym541f0BQ9/PXIlVzrkXp4VQoPqJIQUY0q32EqpfU+Dd6aJSekLLfzlaaBG+6v8nCkm66codx/73V4aHuG2jHCbRyd+ARs9ceE=)

Runs as a function within the repl.

- `2$'` right-pad each individual character of the input to length 2, i.e. append a space
- `,/` flatten the resulting list of strings into a single string and (implicitly) return

If input *must* be read from STDIN, the following suffices for 9 bytes:

```
,/2$'*0:`
```

It is the same as above, but takes a line of input from STDIN via `` *0:` ``.

Answer (score 0):

## Elixir, <s>55</s> 43

```
Regex.replace(~r/(.)\n?/,IO.gets(""),"\\0 ")
```

Sadly, stripping the newline is pretty costly in terms of characters (not sure if I can remove it).

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 5 bytes

```
U¬¸+S
```

[Try it here.](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=Vay4K1M=&input=ImFzZGYi)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 35 chars

Full program

```
alert(prompt().replace(/./g,"$& "))
```

## Javascript ES6, 24 chars

Just a function

```
s=>s.replace(/./g,"$& ")
```

Comment: As we are using a leaderboard right now, would you mind modifying your title for just "Javascript", as it will actually be considered as an other language.

Comment: @Katenkyo, updated

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge-93, 18 bytes

```
>~:1`#v_@
^," ",<
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.7, 62 Bytes

Yes, I know this is not as competitive with most of the other answers, but I wanted to use zip in some sort of way.

```python
i=input();j=''.join;print(j([j(z)for z in zip(i,' '*len(i))]))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Befunge-98, 21 bytes

```
>  ~:av
^,*84,w
@,*84,<
```

Lengthier than one already present but has the ending space requested by OP.

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab/Octave, 51 bytes

```
s=s(.5:.5:length(s))
s(1:2:length(s))=' '
```

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, 18 bytes

```
@(s)[s;32+0*s](:)'
```

Creates an anonymous function. Can then be run using `ans('input string')`

Same rationale as [my MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77948/51939). Takes advantage of the fact that you can flatten `(:)` an array in Octave prior to assignment to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 25 bytes

```
@(s)reshape([s;0*s],1,[])
```

Creates an anonymous function that can be then called using `ans('input string')`.

Exploits that fact that a null character is displayed as a space in MATLAB. Therefore `[s;0*s]` appends a new row that is all spaces. Then using `reshape` flattens this back out into a string but the spaces are inter-spersed due to the row-major ordering.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>21</s></sub> 19 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vba
?StrConv([A1],64)"
```

-1 Byte for removing `&` in `?` statement

-1 Byte for removing terminal `"` from `" "`

Answer (score 0):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src), 8 bytes (noncompeting)

```
⍞ηυ←2Ġ'←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638//9R77xz28@3PmqbYHRkgTqQ@v8/uKQ0Le0/AA)

Explanation:

- `1E/⍞` - receive a line of input from STDIN
- `57/η` - split into individual characters
- `58/υ` - joined by spaces
- `26/←` - print to STDOUT without a newline
- `02/2` - push 2 to the stack
- `25/Ġ` - hexadecimal shift (pop n; push 16n. 2 * 16 is 32, which is the ASCII codepoint of the space)
- `28/'` - convert to character (The space character, `υ` doesn't add a space to the end of the string)
- `26/←` - output with no newline

I originally was thinking of using a vecify command (would have cost a lot of bytes) but then I remembered I had the nice little `υ`.

Answer (score 0):

## [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/), 37 bytes

```
Loop,Parse,1
Send,%A_LoopField%{VK20}
```

The variable `1` is the first passed argument. `{VK20}` is a space.

Answer (score 0):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 363 bytes

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.[a]Go to Chop Suey:n 1 r 1 l 4 r 1 l.Switch to plan "z" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Zoom Zoom:n 1 l 3 r." " is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:w.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.Switch to plan "a".[z]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZA9C8JADIb/ysstbgd@TF0VHBUcBIvDUa41WC/HXUrVP1/7oVIHBYck8JI8bxIxV2qaNUMYW46CTZ5TZpMaU5RthK7qLWXnysPAmxitK2xAweSKbmp5Yo9dZW86NccB9JYS90Jg8UTtapLs1HX50jiouwLlcAx2FhRRG5KW/NNytKgeHA/Mlz71jiXmCFpBjYAwgn0gsWESsbKe5Tn6KSb1n87jpw3Xzr5capRO78emeQA)

Un-golfed / formatted:

```
Go to Post Office: west 1st left 1st right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.
[a]
Go to Chop Suey: north 1st right 1st left 4th right 1st left.
Switch to plan "z" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Zoom Zoom: north 1st left 3rd right.
" " is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Writer's Depot: west.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: north 1st right 2nd right 1st left.
Switch to plan "a".
[z]
```

Nothing fancy here. It's just an old challenge that Taxi is able to easily handle, a rare thing at times.

Answer (score 0):

## **Rust, 49 Bytes**

```
|mut x:String|{x.replace(""," ");x.remove(0);x}
```

it is an anonymous function, or lambda.
It gets input from x, then modifies and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 71 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
S	I LEN(1) . X REM . I :F(O)
	O =O X ' ' :(S)
O	OUTPUT =O
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvLCoMwFETX5itmV4UiFLoS3FVBaE2pCt3exrQJhFhM7OPr7YUyizNzYIKfbpPbr2vSoGza89CLjuuxatNdhhxXXKoTs0FRpzITiUQp2W44RdplQiZy6PnGWlTtYV3rxTm87RgNov5E2PBnNBRhKIAQnqQ06B71DP3S8xfK0EyK9xbWK7eM1j/4oeEoRExe5z8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), 45 bytes

```swift
{$0.map{"\($0) "}.joined()}as(String)->String
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYwxDsIwEAS/srIobAmiFLRQ8gFampNzxkbGiewLAUV5u7GUZne2mC1LcHKukQUOl7oe@u5N06oe@tAbqK17jSHxoM1GRd8lh/Q0p@sOdWop2ml1m2PEEgbxEP4KQtlbPAk8FRDKRJZBTjiDP5x/sJ4y2baPCMnGeWiXzWBEKoIxcaeMqX8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Standard ML (Mlton)](http://www.mlton.org/), 34 bytes

```ml
String.translate(fn c=>str c^" ");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fco7DoAgFATA3lNsqLTQCxC8hL0JUVGSBxpYP7dHnXpykDYI91jKwOTj2jHZmMVyqV3EZPrMhGlUUI0ulxU4GHjq6vg2UTsod4rg9jM3cHn4xxc) It turns out `translate : (char -> string) -> string -> string` from the `String` library is exactly the function needed for this task. The lambda `fn c=>str c^" "` takes a char, converts it to a string with the function `str` and prepends it to the string `" "`. `translate` applies this function to all chars and combines the resulting strings to a single string.

---

Other versions I found before stumbling over the `translate` function:

```ml
String.concatWith" "o map str o explode;
concat o map(fn c=>str c^" ")o explode;
foldr(fn(c,s)=>str c^" "^s)""o explode;
String.concatWithMap" "str o explode;    (* only in SML/NJ *)
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 39 bytes

```
LINPUT A$WHILE""<A$?SHIFT(A$);" ";
WEND
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 8 bytes

```
~Wi@j '~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/78uPNMhS0G97v9/j9ScnHwdhfL8opwURQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 44 bytes

```cs
for(int c;-1<(c=Read());Write((char)c+" "));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/Lb9IIzOvRCHZWtfQRiPZNig1MUVDU9M6vCizJFVDIzkjsUgzWVtJQQko9v@/W2lOjkJ4ZkpJhkJIakUJAA)

Not the first C# submission :) But it follows the challenge to the letter in terms of using `STDIN` and `STDOUT`.

Answer (score 0):

## Japt `-P`, 2 bytes

```
ïS
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=71M=&input=IkZ1bGwgd2lkdGggdGV4dCBpcyB0ZXh0IHRoYXQgaGFzIGEgc3BhY2UgYWZ0ZXIgZXZlcnkgY2hhcmFjdGVyLCBpbmNsdWRpbmcgdGhlIGxhc3Qgb25lLiIKLVA=)

```
ï      :Cartesian product with
 S     :  Space
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C#](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 105 bytes

```
public class P{public static void Main(string[]a){foreach(char c in a[0]){System.Console.Write(c+" ");}}}
```

EDIT: Removed space between string[] and a, also removed ToString as its not crucial saving a total of 12 bytes

Comment: This is a snippet. Answers on this site are required to be full programs or functions.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry!!!

Comment: The parameter passed through string[] a in C# is an array of all arguments. I just get index 0 (first parameter). That's valid input.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused by the fact that you failed to update the try online link when you edited your code.

Comment: You can save 14 bytes by removing `public` keywords

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 44 bytes

Version reading an argument

```cs
Write(string.Join(" ",Args[0].ToList())+" ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY27CgIxEEV/5bLVBtfgL9hYiKVgsVgM2XEzEBLJzPr4@hiwupwDhxt0H1Rau1UxHtWq5NWfi@RxwDAd66rz4e6v5SJqo3O7bl1r7bSlhLcsFmH8MYj@1yIZIikI@qTAoIdxBb@4fhEiVQqdJ0gOaVv6Vy8YidRQMvsf)

## 47 bytes

Version reading standard input

```cs
Write(string.Join(" ",ReadLine().ToList())+" ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1LCgIxEAWv8phVgmOO4UJmJYLrJmlNQ0gk3ePn9DHg6lEUxYt6jCpj3LoYO7Uu9RHOTapbsKwXprRJZefDtW2i5rw/TOHHOO2l4C3JMow/BtH/WiZDJgVBnxQZdDfu4Bf3L2KmTnHyCqmx7Gm@zYJRSA2tcvgB)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
ðâJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcvBDYMwEETRVqaAKGXkQBcTs8QrWQZ510lohwrowYUZS5y@3uGvxrdK7@1sx9T7q6aEn84e4fJ3qN31SEekgbCNQcDFpUC@UnaEyMIw/IDmkOqs@TMOQaI51izPCw)

```
ðâJ  # full program
  J  # join...
 â   # cartesian product of...
     # implicit input...
 â   # and...
ð    # " "
     # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## BRASCA, 10 bytes

```
![aEmmA{]x
```

[Try it online!](https://sjoerdpennings.github.io/brasca-online/?code=!%5BaEmmA%7B%5Dx&stdin=This%20is%20full-width%20text!)

### Explanation

```
!           - Push stack length
 [a   A{]   - For i in range(0,stack_length)
   E        - Push a space
    mm      - Shift the stack twice
         x  - Remove the excess 0
<implicit>  - Output the stack reversed
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 16 bytes

```sh
<<<${${1/// }# }
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGpVql2lBfX1@hVlmh9v///xmpOTn5AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `sequences.interleaved`, 29 bytes

```
readln 32 <interleaved> print
```

Modern versions of Factor (i.e. not TIO) allow most sequences to be `print`ed as strings. So have a screenshot of running this in the listener:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ðṖ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpdS7IKlpSVpuhZLD294uHPakuKk5GKoyIKb4W6lOTkK5ZkpJRkKJakVJQqZxRC6JCOxRCEjsVghUaG4IDE5VSExrSS1SCG1LLWoUiE5I7EoMRnI11HIzEvOKU3JzEsH6khVyEksLlHIz0vVg5gPAA)

Port of Dennis's Jelly answer: cartesian product with space. `J` flag joins the list.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 30 Bytes

```python
lambda x:' '.join(list(x))+' '
```

[`T r y   i t   o n l i n e !`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCSl1BXS8rPzNPIyezuESjQlNTGyjyv6AoM69EI00jM6@gtERDU1Pzf2JSckqqQnl@OQQAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 43 bytes

```
listen to S
cut S
join S with " "
say S+" "
```

[Try it](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 3.5 bytes (7 nibbles)

```
+.@:$" "
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWK7T1HKxUlBSUIFyo6ILNIRmpCoWlmcnZCklF-eV5Cmn5FRApAA)

#### Explanation

```
+.@:$" "
  @       First line of stdin as a string (list of chars)
 .        Map this function:
    $       To each char,
   :        Append
     " "    A space
+         Concatenate the resulting list of strings together
```

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 17 bytes

```lua
gsub(s,".","%1 ")
```

Full Program.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z@9uDRJo1hHSU9JR0nVUEFJ8////0oeqTk5@ToK4flFOSmKSgA)

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.9, 38 bytes

```swift
let f={($0+"").map{" \($0)"}.joined()}
```