# Make a string a e s t h e t i c

Tags: code-golf, string

Basically, between every character of a uni-line string, add a space, but there can't be two spaces in between one character.

- `aesthetic` becomes `a e s t h e t i c`.
- `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` becomes `T h e q u i c k b r o w n f o x j u m p s o v e r t h e l a z y d o g`.
- `I'm Nobody! Who are you?` becomes `I ' m n o b o d y ! W h o a r e y o u ?`

This is code golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: PS this is my first challenge. Any feedback would be very helpful!

Comment: Would it be acceptable to output one extra trailing space? Will there ever be newlines in the input?

Comment: No newlines, yes to extra space

Comment: We can assume input will always be printable ascii? Can input be a char array?

Comment: @Pavel yes, as always

Comment: Will the input contain Tabs? Should we filter them out?

Comment: @ATaco No, the input will not contain tabs

Comment: I think this question is close enough to [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75979/full-width-text?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) to be a dupe

Comment: Welcome to PPCG.  Since you're asking for feedback - 1) This is a very simple challenge that (as you can see from all the quick, short answers) is trivial to answer in many languages.  2) Consider posting challenges to the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) first to get more constructive feedback before the challenge officially opens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ḟ⁶K
```

`ḟ`ilter out spaces (`⁶`) then join by space (`K`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wx/xHjdu8////H5KRqlBYmpmcrZBUlF@ep5CWX6GQVZpbUKyQX5ZapFAClM5JrKpUSMlPBwA)

Comment: Or `ḲFK` for the same byte count.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 36 bytes

```py
lambda s:" ".join(s.replace(" ",""))
```

Comment: Ninja'd me by a byte, I used `lambda s:" ".join(''.join(s.split()))` :P

Comment: 31: `print(*input().replace(' ',''))`

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, 8

```
 

.
$0
```

Whitespace is significant - there are single spaces at the end of the first and last lines.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#Dcq9DkAwFAbQ/T7FJ5HYxBuYLSaJufRSv5dS1MuXM58AopTiDCEoPk7D59BSZRi7G9oJjZV7RScPRrdsB@Rii39hVq@Hlp6KZEEpjWgfoTYCZRleXP4B).

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 4 bytes

```
jdsc
```

Splitting on whitespace and then joining seems shorter than removing the spaces.

In pseudocode:

```python
'     ' d,Q = " ",input()  # preinitialized variables
'jd   ' d.join(
'  s  '     sum(
'   cQ'         Q.split() ))
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jdsc&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22aesthetic%22%0A%22The+quick+brown+fox+jumps+over+the+lazy+dog%22%0A%22I%27m+Nobody%21+Who+are+you%3F%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 22 bytes

```haskell
(((:" ")=<<)=<<).words
```

Laikoni saved 2 bytes with a nice use of `words`. Previous answer:

```haskell
(=<<)(:" ").filter(>' ')
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@59mq2FrY6OpYaWkoKSpl5aZU5JapGGnrqCu@T83MTNPwVahoLQkuKRIQUUhTUEpUQEIkhSSlf4DAA)

Comment: `(((:" ")=<<)=<<).words` is two bytes shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 7 bytes

```
Íó*/ 
X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3@49/BmLX0Froj//zNSc3LyFcrzi3JSAA)

Just a straightforward regex, and an "X" to delete one leading space.

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 28

```
puts [split [join $s ""] ""]
```

testable on http://rextester.com/VFP77495