# Print all digits of an integer

Tags: integer, fastest-code, fastest-algorithm

### Challenge

Given a positive integer, find the fastest way to iterate over its digits. Bytecode size doesn't matter as much as speed of execution.

### Examples

For 6875, the program would output `6 8 7 5`.

For 199182, it would output `1 9 9 1 8 2`.

For 0, it would output `0`.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Your first question is OK, however it is way too trivial, and almost all answers will be identical. I don't see any faster solution than the obvious here. I recommend you read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions and try posting competitive answers too.

Comment: Hey @Makonede! Happy to close the question. I just wanted to get a taste of CG and I posted the first challenge that crossed my mind.

Comment: Please note that you'd have to choose either fastest code (fastest runtime speed) or fastest algorithm (smallest asymptotic time complexity). You cannot use both. You probably want the latter but, as pointed out by Makonede, neither makes much sense for this task.

Comment: How much algorithms are for this?

Comment: [Dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75979/full-width-text)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 15 bytes (Courtesy of @Makonede)

```python
print(*input())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQyszr6C0RENT8/9/AwA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 24 bytes (~0.03s)

```python
print(' '.join(input()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ11BXS8rPzNPIzOvoLREQ1NT8/9/MwtzSwA)

Should be compact and fast

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 23 bytes

```powershell
("$args"|% t*y)-join' '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0NJJbEovVipRlWhRKtSUzcrPzNPXUH9/38zC3NLMAEA)

This dosen't deserve seperate answer

Comment: Even though golfage doesn't matter here, `print(*input())` is 9 bytes shorter :)

Comment: @Makonede thanks! I'll edit later

Comment: Also, since this is [tag:fastest-code] you should probably include the average execution time in the header before the bytecount: ~0.03s

Comment: @Makonede how can I calculate execution time

Comment: Also i am posting all answers in one answers because they are trivial

Comment: Execution time is shown under `Real time` in the `Debug` section of TIO

Comment: @Makonede its not accurate, maybe Sys. time?

Comment: I guess, but it's fine, this challenge is probably gonna be closed soon anyway - EDIT: closed

Comment: **8 bytes:** [`' '.join`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzX11BXS8rPzPvf0FRZl6JRppGZl5BaYmGpqbmf0NLS0MLIwA "Python 3 – Try It Online") (once again, not that golfage matters but might as well :))