# Forecast Palindromic Dates

Tags: code-golf, date, palindrome

[Palindromic dates](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/special-dates.html) are dates that appear as palindromes: the string of digits can be read the same way backwards as forwards. For the North American date format (MM/DD/YYYY), the next few palindromic dates are:

`02/02/2020`

`12/02/2021`

`03/02/2030`

#### The Challenge

Create a function that returns all palindromic dates in a consistent, common date format (of your choosing) that fall within a range of dates (*edit: including the range itself*).

#### Rules

- To qualify as a palindrome, only the numeric characters of the date should be
  checked.
- The date can be in any common format (`MM/DD/YYYY`, `DD-MM-YYYY`), as
  long as it uses two digits for both the month and day and four for
  the year, and it uses a character to separate parts of the date. The output must preserve seperating characters (`/`, `-`, etc.). Your function only needs to handle one distinct date format. Please include the format in your answer.
- If there are more than one dates returned, they should be comma or
  new-line separated.
- Shortest answer wins!

#### Example

```
date_palindrome('05/02/2050', '12/12/2060')
>>>['05/02/2050', '06/02/2060']
```

Comment: If i want to post a  Oracle SQL answer can I use the input type `DATE` avoiding a `to_date()` or I have to use the less golfable `VARCHAR2`?

Comment: I don't know enough about Oracle SQL to answer this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## MATL, <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
YOZ}&:"@23XOtt47>)tP=?8M
```

Accepts  input in the form of an array of string `{lower, upper}` where the date format is `'MM/DD/YYYY'`. Output is in the format `MM/DD/YYYY` as well.

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WU9afSY6IkAyM1hPdDQ3Pil0UD0_OE0&input=eycwMS8wMi8yMDIwJywnMTIvMTIvMjAyMSd9Cg)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab the two inputs
YO      % Convert to serial date format
Z}      % Push them onto the stack separately
&:      % Create an array from [lower...upper] incrementing 1 day
"       % For each day
  @23XO % Get the string version of the date (mm/dd/yyyy)
  tt    % Duplicate twice
  47>)  % Get the numeric parts
  tP=   % Compare numeric part with the flipped version of the numeric part
  ?8M   % If they are the same push it to the stack
        % Implicitly display stack contents
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 197 bytes

One byte saved thanks to @cat!

```python
from datetime import*
def g(a,b):
 for s in"ab":exec"%s=date(*[int(x)for x in %s.split('-')])"%(s,s)
 for d in range((b-a).days+1):
    x=str(a+timedelta(d));y=x.replace("-","")
    if y==y[::-1]:print x
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/C5Z9/2)

Input and output format is `YYYY-MM-DD`. First intendation level is spaces, second one is tabs.
Nothing too special going on here. Uses some `exec` abuse to convert the input to `date` objects by splitting the date string on `-` and splatting the list into the `date` constructor. Then we just iterate over all dates in their inclusive range and print the ones which are palindromic.

Comment: Put the `from datetime import*` on the first line to save a byte

Comment: Not sure, but does `\`a+timedelta(d)\`` the same as `str(a+timedelta(d))`?

Comment: @Mathias711 Unfortunately not, `repr` is usually only equivalent to `str` for primitive datatypes. For `date` objects I get `datetime.date(2012, 12, 12)` for instance.

Answer (score 6):

## Bash + GNU utilities, <strike>116</strike> 84

Requires 64-bit version of date for the given testcase.

```bash
set date -uf- +%
jot -w@ - `$@s` 86400|$@F|sed -r 'h
:
s/-|^(.)(.*)\1$/\2/
t
/./d
g'
```

I/O is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.  Input is taken from two lines of stdin, e.g.

```bash
printf "%s\n" 2050-05-02 2060-12-12 | ./palindate.sh
```

#### Explanation

- `set` saves the date command template so it may be accessed using the `$@` parameter
- `date -uf- +%s` converts endpoint dates to number of seconds since the Unix epoch
- `jot` interpolates this to give a list of seconds-from-the-epoch, one per day, each prefixed with `@`
- `date -uf- +%F` formats each list entry as `YYYY-MM-DD`
- `sed` checks for palindromes:

  - `h` save the input line to the hold buffer
  - `:` define "unnamed" label
  - `s/-|^(.)(.*)\1$/\2/` if a dash is found, remove it or if the first and last characters match, remove them
  - `t` if there was a match above, jump back to the unnamed label
  - `/./d` if there are any characters left over, the line is not a palindrome - delete it and continue to the next line
  - `g` if we got here, then no line deletion happened, thus the line must have been a palindrome.  Get the line back from the hold buffer and implicitly display it.

Answer (score 5):

### PowerShell v2+, 127 bytes

```
for($a,$b=[datetime[]]$args;$a-le$b){if(($c="{0:yyyyMMdd}"-f$a)-eq-join$c[$c.length..0]){"{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"-f$a}$a=$a.AddDays(1)}
```

Takes input as command-line arguments `$args` in `MM/DD/YYYY` (or similar) format and recasts as a `[datetime]` array, stores them in `$a` and `$b`. That's the setup step of the `for` loop. The conditional is so long as `$a` is less-than-or-equal-to `$b`.

Each iteration, we set `$c` equal to a `-f`ormatted string of `yyyyMMdd` style, based on `$a`. We then compare if that's `-eq`ual to `$c` reversed (using an array-join trick). If so, we output `$a` in the proper format. Either way, we increment `$a` with `.AddDays(1)` to move to the next day.

#### Example

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\forecast-palindromic-dates.ps1 '06/23/2016' '12/12/2020'
02/02/2020
```

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 132 bytes

```
f(a,b,t=s->DateTime(s,"mm/dd/y"),g=d->Dates.format(d,"mm/dd/yyyy"))=map(g,filter(d->(r=replace(g(d),"/",""))==reverse(r),t(a):t(b)))
```

This is a function that accepts two strings and returns an array of strings.

Ungolfed:

```
function f(a, b)
    # Define a function to create a DateTime object from a string
    t = s -> DateTime(s, "mm/dd/y")

    # Define a function to create a string from a DateTime object
    g = d -> Dates.format(d, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    # Filter the range a:b to palindromic dates
    p = filter(d -> (r = replace(g(d), "/", "")) == reverse(r), t(a):t(b))

    # Format all dates in the array
    m = map(g, p)

    return m
end
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=ZihhLGIsdD1zLT5EYXRlVGltZShzLCJtbS9kZC95IiksZz1kLT5EYXRlcy5mb3JtYXQoZCwibW0vZGQveXl5eSIpKT1tYXAoZyxmaWx0ZXIoZC0-KHI9cmVwbGFjZShnKGQpLCIvIiwiIikpPT1yZXZlcnNlKHIpLHQoYSk6dChiKSkpCgpwcmludGxuKGYoIjAyLzAyLzIwMjAiLCAiMDMvMDIvMjAzMCIpKQ&input=)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>159</s> 154 bytes

```
(s,e)=>{for(r=[],s=Date.parse(s),e=Date.parse(e);s<=e;s+=864e5){d=new Date(s).toJSON().slice(0,10);`${a=d.match(/\d/g)}`==a.reverse()&&r.push(d)}return r}
```

I/O in ISO format. Ungolfed:

```
function date_palindrome(start, end) {
    start = Date.parse(start);
    end = Date.parse(end);
    var result = [];
    while (start <= end) {
        var date = new Date(start).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
        var digits = date.match(/d/g);
        if (digits.join() == digits.reverse.join()) {
            result.push(date);
        }
        start += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // ms
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, <s>436</s> <s>435</s> 416 bytes **sigh..**

```
import java.text.*;import java.util.*;void c(String...a)throws Exception{DateFormat f=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");Calendar s=Calendar.getInstance(),e=Calendar.getInstance();s.setTime(f.parse(a[0]));e.setTime(f.parse(a[1]));for(Date d=s.getTime();s.before(e);s.add(5,1),d=s.getTime()){String o=f.format(d),x=o.replaceAll("\\W|_",""),w="";for(char c:x.toCharArray())w=c+w;if(x.equals(w))System.out.println(o);}}
```

**Input & Output format:** `dd-MM-yyyy`

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/wDlNL2)

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main{
  static void c(String... a) throws Exception{
    DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Calendar s = Calendar.getInstance(),
             e = Calendar.getInstance();
    s.setTime(f.parse(a[0]));
    e.setTime(f.parse(a[1]));
    for(Date d = s.getTime(); s.before(e); s.add(Calendar.DATE, 1), d = s.getTime()){
      String o = f.format(d),
             x = o.replaceAll("\\W|_", ""),
             w = "";
      for(char c : x.toCharArray()){
        w = c + w;
      }
      if(x.equals(w)){
        System.out.println(o);
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    try{
      c("05-02-2050", "12-12-2060");
    } catch (Exception e){}
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
05-02-2050
15-02-2051
25-02-2052
06-02-2060
```

Comment: [+1. Cause, y'know, Java.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5829/46231)

Comment: @cat Thanks for the comment I guess, but you forgot to actually +1 the answer. ;P

Comment: Well, actually, my lazy browser didn't feel like agreeing that I +1'd and so when I refresh, bam, my vote is gone D:

Answer (score 2):

## TSQL, 88 bytes

Using ISO8601 format for date(yyyy-mm-dd)

```
DECLARE @ date='2050-05-02',@t date='2060-12-12'

a:IF stuff(reverse(@),3,1,'')=stuff(@,8,1,'')PRINT @
SET @=dateadd(d,1,@)IF @<=@t GOTO a
```

[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/503725/forecast-palindromic-dates)

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle 11: SQL:  246 bytes** (hey, at least I beat Java :P lol )

```
with d as(select to_date('&1','yyyy-mm-dd')s,to_date('&2','yyyy-mm-dd')e from dual),r as(select level-1 l from d connect by level<=e-s+1),x as(select s+l y,to_char(s+l,'yyyymmdd')w from d,r)select to_char(y,'yyyy-mm-dd')from x where w=reverse(w);
```

**Output:**

```
  SQL> with d as(select to_date('&1','yyyy-mm-dd')s,to_date('&2','yyyy-mm-dd')e from dual),r as(select level-1 l from d connect by level<=e-s+1),x as(select s+l y,to_char(s+l,'yyyymmdd')w from d,r)select to_char(y,'yyyy-mm-dd')from x where w=reverse(w);
  Enter value for 1: 2000-01-01
  Enter value for 2: 2021-01-01

  TO_CHAR(Y,
  ----------
  2001-10-02
  2010-01-02
  2011-11-02
  2020-02-02

  SQL>
```

**In readable format:**

```
  with d as (select to_date('&1','yyyy-mm-dd') s,
                    to_date('&2','yyyy-mm-dd') e
              from dual),
        r as (select level-1 l 
                from d connect by level <= e-s+1),
        x as (select s+l y, to_char(s+l,'yyyymmdd') w 
                from d,r)
  select to_char(y,'yyyy-mm-dd')
    from x 
   where w=reverse(w);
```

**Explained:**

```
d: get input for start/end
r: generate rows needed, 1 per day.
x: calculate the actual dates, and convert them to a minimal string.
final: use REVERSE function to verify the palindroms, return in proper format.
```

Learned about the REVERSE function today :)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>97</s> 94 bytes

```
(a,b)=>{for(;a<b;a=a.AddDays(1))if($"{a:yyy}".SequenceEqual($"{a:MMdd}".Reverse()))a.Dump();};
```

C# lambda (`Action`) where inputs are `DateTime` and the output is printed by using the `.Dump()` method (@EvilFonti's [trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/33114/15214)).

---

## C#, <s>115</s> 112 bytes

```
(a,b)=>{var r="";for(;a<b;a=a.AddDays(1))if($"{a:yyy}".SequenceEqual($"{a:MMdd}".Reverse()))r+=a+",";return r;};
```

C# lambda (`Func`) where inputs are `DateTime` and output is a `string`.

Code:

```
(a,b)=> {
    var r="";
    for(;a<b;a=a.AddDays(1)) {
        if($"{a:yyy}".SequenceEqual($"{a:MMdd}".Reverse()))
            r+=a+",";
    }
    return r;
};
```

---

[Try them online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HcxgPg)

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, <strike>240</strike> 193 bytes

```
Function f(a, b)
Dim j, g()
For i = CDate(a) To CDate(b)
    If Format(i, "yyyy") = StrReverse(Format(i, "mmdd")) Then
        ReDim Preserve g(j)
        g(j) = Format(i, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next
f = g()
End Function
```

That's it in a comprehensible format. Test case:

```
Sub e()
MsgBox Join(f("5/2/2050", "6/2/2060"), ", ")
End Sub
```

Without that much redundancy:

```
Function f(a,b)
Dim j, g()
For i=CDate(a) To CDate(b)
If Format(i,"yyyy")=StrReverse(Format(i,"mmdd")) Then
ReDim Preserve g(j)
g(j)=Format(i,"yyyy-mm-dd")
j=j+1
End If
Next
f=g()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript (using external library) (158 bytes)

```
(a,b)=>_.RangeTo(a%1e20,b%1e20,864e5).Select(y=>new Date(y)).Where(x=>z=(_.From(x.toJSON()).Where(y=>!isNaN(y)).Take(8)).SequenceEqual(z.Reverse())).ToArray()
```

Link to lib: https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable

Code explanation: Ok, I finally used some actual code golfing here for once. So the inputs a,b are Date objects. Create a range of integers from a to b, where a and b are coerced into integers, and the distance between values in the range is 86400000, i.e the amount of ticks in one day. Map each value in the range to a date object. Filter that range by the predicate that represents palindromic dates. The logic to determine that is simple...cast the JSON string representation of the current date object to a char array using the library and filter out the non-numeric entries, and only take the first 8 values (because the that would be yyyyMMdd) and store that into variable z, then check if z is equivalent to z Reversed. Finally, cast back to native JS array

Edit: Shaved 2 bytes by removing unnecessary parens..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 269 bytes

```
import java.time.LocalDate;void q(String...a)throws Exception{LocalDate s=LocalDate.parse(a[0]);while(!s.isAfter(LocalDate.parse(a[1]))){String d=s.toString().replace("-","");if(d.equals(new StringBuffer(d).reverse().toString()))System.out.println(d);s=s.plusDays(1);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class UnGolfedPalindromicDates {
    public static void main(String...a) throws IOException {
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse(a[0]), end = LocalDate.parse(a[1]);
        while (!start.isAfter(end)) {
            String d = start.toString().replace("-","");
            if (palindrome(d)) System.out.println(d);
            start = start.plusDays(1);
        }
    }

    public static boolean palindrome(String s) {
        return s.equals(new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString());
    }
}
```