# Directory calculation

Tags: code-golf, string, file-system

For this challenge, you will be given an absolute path, and a "new" path (which can be absolute or relative), and you need to return the final path.

For example, if your current directory was `/var/tmp/test`:

`my_dir` or `my_dir/`  should return `/var/tmp/test/my_dir`

`../../my_dir` should return `/var/my_dir`

`/my_dir/./` should return `/my_dir`

`../../../../../` should return `/`

To be more pedantic:

- A directory is a non-empty string consisting of alphanumeric characters and the symbols `-`,`_`, or `.`
- **A path is a list of 0 or more directories**, separated using `/`.  An absolute path starts with a `/`, a relative path does not.  Paths can include an ending `/`.

You need to "resolve" the second path, given the first path.

The process of resolving is:

1. Test if the second path is relative.  If so, then insert the absolute path's directories to the beginning of the second path.
2. If any of the directories is `..`, then remove it and the preceding directory.  If it is the first directory, then simply remove it.
3. If any of the directories is `.`, then remove it.
4. Output the final absolute path.  You should not output an ending `/`.

You do not need to handle incorrect input.  The commands should work, whether or not the directories passed actually exist on your machine.  You can assume that everything is a directory, even if it has an extension.

## Test cases

```
Absolute      New          Output
"/a/b/c"      "d"       -> "/a/b/c/d" 
"/a/b/c/"     "d"       -> "/a/b/c/d"
"/a/b/c/"     "d/"      -> "/a/b/c/d"
"/a/b/c"      "/d"      -> "/d"
"/a/b/c"      "/d/"     -> "/d"
"/../a/b/c/"  "d"       -> "/a/b/c/d"
"/a/../b/c/"  "d"       -> "/b/c/d"
"/a/b/../c"   "d"       -> "/a/c/d"
"/a/b/c/.."   "d"       -> "/a/b/d"
"/a/b/c/"     ".."      -> "/a/b"
"/a/b/c"      "../d"    -> "/a/b/d"
"/a/b/c"      "/../d"   -> "/d"
"/a/b/c"      ""        -> "/a/b/c"
"/a/b/c"      "."       -> "/a/b/c"
"/a/b/c"      "./d"     -> "/a/b/c/d"
"/a/b/c"      "/./d"    -> "/d"
"/a/b/c"      "d.txt"   -> "/a/b/c/d.txt"
"/a/b/c"      "d."      -> "/a/b/c/d."
"/a/b/c"      ".txt"    -> "/a/b/c/.txt"
"/a/b/c"      ".txt/d"  -> "/a/b/c/.txt/d"
"/a/b/."      "./././." -> "/a/b"
"/direc"      "tory"    -> "/direc/tory"
"/a-_.b/"     "__._-."  -> "/a-_.b/__._-."
"/a/b"        "../.."   -> "/"
"/a/b"        "../../.."-> "/"
"/a"          "../../.."-> "/"
"/"           ""        -> "/"
"/"           "a"       -> "/a"
"/.."         "a"       -> "/a"
"/."          ""        -> "/"
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so make your submissions as short as possible in your favorite language!

Comment: Some answers appear to assume that *files* (or symlinks) with the same name as any part of the directory tree) do *not* exist on the machine. Is that allowed?

Comment: Can we take the two inputs in any order we wish?

Comment: Stupid question... can I have side effects? Specifically, side effects like, um, `mkdir $patha; cd $patha; mkdir $pathb; cd $pathb; echo \`abspath\`` (or something)?

Comment: @dennis. The output of the programs should be independent of the file system

Comment: @downgoat that's fine

Comment: @cat side effects are fine.

Answer (score 7):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 44 bytes

```
+`.+ /| |/\.?/
/
+1`/?[^/]*/\.\.|/\.?$

^$
/
```

Input is expected to be the two paths separated by a single space.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAorYC4rIC98IHwvXC4_LwovCisxYC8_W14vXSovXC5cLnwvXC4_JAoKXiQKLw&input=L2EvYi9jIGQKL2EvYi9jLyBkCi9hL2IvYy8gZC8KL2EvYi9jIC9kCi9hL2IvYyAvZC8KLy4uL2EvYi9jLyBkCi9hLy4uL2IvYy8gZAovYS9iLy4uL2MgZAovYS9iL2MvLi4gZAovYS9iL2MvIC4uCi9hL2IvYyAuLi9kCi9hL2IvYyAvLi4vZAovYS9iL2MgCi9hL2IvYyAuCi9hL2IvYyAuL2QKL2EvYi9jIC8uL2QKL2EvYi9jIGQudHh0Ci9hL2IvYyBkLgovYS9iL2MgLnR4dAovYS9iL2MgLnR4dC9kCi9hL2IvLiAuLy4vLi8uCi9kaXJlYyB0b3J5Ci9hLV8uYi8gX18uXy0uCi9hL2IgLi4vLi4KL2EvYiAuLi8uLi8uLgovYSAuLi8uLi8uLgovLiAKL2EvYi9jIC4vLi4vLi8uLg) (The first line enables a linefeed-separated test suite.)

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, <s>282</s> <s>281</s> <s>279</s> 276 bytes

```
@echo off
set a=\
set r=%~2
if "%r%"=="" set r=%~1
if not %r:~,1%==/ set r=%~1/%~2
for %%a in (%r:/= %)do call:x %%a
if not %a%==\ set a=%a:~,-1%
echo %a:\=/%
exit/b
:x
if %1==. exit/b
if not %1==.. set a=%a%%1\&exit/b
if not %a%==\ for %%a in (%a:~,-1%)do set a=%%~pa
```

Annoyingly Batch expressions don't generally like empty variables. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ and 2 bytes thanks to @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ (and a bunch of bytes on other answers too, although alas uncredited).

Comment: I think you can remove a space between `call` and :x`, no?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Huh, so you can. I've got a bunch of answers that need updating in that case...

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 53 bytes

```
from os.path import*;p=lambda a,n:normpath(join(a,n))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>265</s> <s>260</s> 254 bytes

```
y=lambda:[x for x in raw_input().split("/")if x!=""and x!="."]
a=y();n=y();m=len(a)-1
while m>0:
 if a[m]==".."and m>0:del a[m];del a[m-1];m-=1
 elif a[m]=="..":del a[m]
 m-=1
for i in n:
 if i==".."and len(a)>0:del a[-1]
 else:a+=i,
print"/"+"/".join(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 43 bytes

```
(x,y)=>Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(x,y));
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to @aloisdg

`Path.Combine` puts the arguments together, and `Path.GetFullPath` resolves the `..\`s

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! This is not a valid program -- either include `main` and a class, or change it to a lanbda: `a,b->`...

Comment: I was going to post it :) Nice first submission! you can remove the space after the `,`: `(x, y)` => `(x,y)`

Comment: Also the [C# Tips for golfing thread](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c?answertab=active#tab-top) may interest you.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 41 bytes

This bash script has the side effect of creating directories if they don't exist, but it should meet the requirements.  Thanks [Karl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85479/directory-calculation#comment209832_85500) and [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85479/directory-calculation#comment209847_85500) for your improvements.

```
mkdir -p $1;cd $1;mkdir -p $2;cd "$2";pwd
```

Usage: *bash getpath.sh "absolute" "new"*

If you don't like the stderr when second argument is an empty string, you can test for it as follows (48 bytes):

```
mkdir -p $1;cd $1;[ $2 ]&&mkdir -p $2&&cd $2;pwd
```

Previous 30 byte attempt (requires directories to exist):
<s>*cd $1;[ $2 ]&&cd $2;echo `pwd`*</s>

Comment: The question says *The commands should work, whether or not the directories passed actually exist on your machine.*

Comment: Ah, I see. Too bad.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! Normally, if your answer doesn't work, you delete it. You can click the delete link above this comment.

Comment: You could `mkdir -p` to make sure they exist.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying a version with mkdir.  I'll delete this answer and add a new one if I figure it out.

Comment: Thanks Karl, it works now if run with the necessary permissions.

Comment: Why not use `pwd` instead of `echo \`pwd\``?

Comment: As `stderr` is ignored by default, you can use `mkdir -p $2;cd "$2"`. (`cd $2` wouldn't work of course.)

Comment: Thanks Neil, those are some good improvements.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Bryn I don't think you're supposed to add a new answer as a replacement of this one. This one must be replaced if it doesn't work. (FYI I know it's edited now)

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Sorry, should I make a new answer now?  I thought it would be useful to have the comment history so I edited my old answer.  By the way, are there posting guidelines/FAQ somewhere that I am missing?

Comment: @Bryn Editing and undeleting the existing answer is the preferred way. (I think that's what Erik meant, but I'm not sure.) Posts are never hard-deleted, so they clutter the thread forever. The [help center](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help) has some guidelines.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for the clarification.  Undeleting makes sense.

Comment: @Bryn That's what I said. Sorry for bad wording, I meant (I don't think you're supposed to add a new answer for the same language as this one, if this one is deleted. Instead, edit this one.)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <strike>142</strike> 137 bytes

```
def p(a,n,r=[],S="/"):
 for s in[s for s in((n[:1]!=S)*a+S+n).split(S)if"."!=s and s]:e=s!="..";r=[s]*e+r[1-e:]
 return S+S.join(r[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

## Node REPL, <s>8</s> 12 bytes

```
path.resolve
```

Luckily you don't have to `require()` standard modules in the REPL.

### Test Suite

https://repl.it/Cclo/1

(If the output at the end is `true`, it matched)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 210 bytes

```
function p(a,b){d='.';e=d+d;s='/';t='split';u='splice';r=(b[0]===s?[]:a[t](s)).concat(b[t](s));for(i=0;i<r.length;r[i]===e&&r[u](i?i-1:i,i?2:1)?(i&&i--):i++)(!r[i]||r[i]===d)&&r[u](i,1)&&i--;return s+r.join(s)}
```

[Here is test suite](https://repl.it/CdPQ/1)

With linebreaks instead of semicolons:

```
function p(a,b) {
    d='.'
    e=d+d
    s='/'
    t='split'
    u='splice'

    r=(b[0]===s?[]:a[t](s)).concat(b[t](s))

    for(i=0;i<r.length;r[i]===e&&r[u](i?i-1:i,i?2:1)?(i&&i--):i++)
        (!r[i]||r[i]===d)&&r[u](i,1)&&i--

    return s+r.join(s)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 83 bytes

```java
String p(String a,String b){return Paths.get(a).resolve(b).normalize().toString();}
```

`normalize` is needed to deal with relative references. `add` is used to handle the second path starting with `/`, which `Paths.get(a, b)` won't handle as specified.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! This is a good first post!

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 38 bytes

```
[[ $2 = /* ]]||p=$1
realpath -sm $p/$2
```

Doesn't require root privileges and makes no assumptions about existing or non-existing files, directories or symbolic links.

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/4z04WP).

#### How it works

`[[ $2 = /* ]]` tests if the second command-line argument begins with `/`.

If it doesn't, the path is relative and `p=$1` sets variable **p** to the first command-line argument.

This way `$p/$2` is `/$2` if `$2` is an absolute path and `$1/$2` if it is a realtive one.

Finally, `realpath -sm $p/$2` prints the canonical absolute path of `$p/$2`. The `-s` switch makes *realpath* ignore symbolic links, and the `-m` switch missing components.

Answer (score 0):

## [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>81</s> 59 + 1 = 60 bytes

+1 byte for `-r` flag. Expects input on STDIN separates by a single space.

```
s:.+ /::
s:/? :/:
:
s:/$|[^/]+/+\.\.|\.(/|$):\1:
t
s:^/*:/:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDBDoIwDIbve4oePKiENl578UGcLMA4cBHDdtCEZ3cWEFazZPn@9u@fpqHzKQXGAojZBKYrMLFZ8DDdKroXVFi0OFk80nQ4sb2widKu6CzOlKimhlrwZgXSRD8E8pmkiPhnFqknRao8RJWIuOWIKWdqsRt20MbMHuMrZrG7VXXmbQAlZ3mGfD92LcRhfEurdNgQOIeuXDPmzVDjqhTLilDPR1h@@AzP2A@PkMrxCw)

### Explanation

```
s:.+ /::  # If the second argument starts with a slash, drop the first argument
s:/? :/:  # Join the first and second arguments with a slash, dropping duplicate slashes
:
  s:/$|[^/]+/+\.\.|\.(/|$):\1:  # Drop trailing slashes, resolve double and single dots
  t                             # If the above substitution was made, branch to :
s:^/*:/:  # Ensure output begins with a single slash
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 16 bytes

Since apparently using [a method from the standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/File.html) is allowed:

```
File.expand_path
```

See the [test suite on repl.it](https://repl.it/CdLW/2).

Comment: Input via variables isn't allowed, but function submission, are, which means that you should shorten it to `File.expand_path` :)

Comment: I'd also recommend actually testing it against the test suite to make sure that it works correctly on all of the test cases.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I did, but I'll go ahead and stick something up on repl.it.

Comment: Edited to include test suite link.

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 15 bytes

```sh
a=$1/$2
<<<$a:a
```

The `:a` modifier does exactly this.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBNCsMgEIX3nmIWbuPQLtv0LKIZIYHSQCr05/LWOLFNo1FB@Jz3xnnvex8e/XB1MDlDYMBCdwYaxd15aBqQBqQN5iIPKI@ibVtpTibQeHMBDVrsIC3iSzDDfYZrxgVINYbMlPrKV36RFszOtCv7KrXzl/Sw6RstqPgLwz8GUNHWGA@38St7kPJPX7CKXyorWXRcMsh90xZIw@SWOj9OL9Y2WlnOALVWulEszlPFeedsShZPhL/xM0yuq1hMTmKJOLEP)