# Shorten an absolute path

Tags: code-golf, string, file-system

Sometimes a long absolute path, in e.g. a command-line parameter to a linux tool, can be shortened, using current working directory as reference:

```
$ pwd
/home/heh

$ cat /home/heh/mydir/myfile
my stuff

$ cat mydir/myfile
my stuff
```

In this challenge, you should make a function or a program that receives two parameters:

1. Absolute path, using the linux format (starts with `/`)
2. Current directory, using the same format

The output is the shorter of the following:

- Input 1 unchanged
- Relative path that refers to the same file/directory as the absolute path

Fine points:

- If your operating system is compatible with linux, you can use the system's current directory instead of receiving it as input
- You can assume the inputs contain only alphanumeric characters (and path separators)
- You can assume the input absolute path doesn't have a path separator `/` at the end
- You can assume the input current directory has a path separator `/` at the end
- You cannot assume that the absolute path refers to an existing file, or that any part of it is an accessible directory; however, the current directory can be assumed valid
- You can assume there are no symlinks anywhere near either path - because I don't want to require any special way of dealing with symlinks
- No need to support the case where either of the inputs is the root directory
- "The current directory" should be output as `.` (an empty string is not valid)

Test cases (input1, input2, output):

```
/home/user/mydir/myfile
/home/user
mydir/myfile

/var/users/admin/secret/passwd
/var/users/joe/hack
../../admin/secret/passwd

/home/user/myfile
/tmp/someplace
/home/user/myfile

/dir1/dir2
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
../..

/dir1/dir2
/dir1/dir2
.
```

Comment: "You can assume the input current directory has a path separator `/` at the end". However, in your examples, this is not the case.

Comment: I like it this way, but some people like it the other way

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85479/42963).

Comment: What should happen if absolute and relative path have the same length?

Comment: If same length, either output is good.

Comment: *You cannot assume that the absolute path refers to an existing file* and *you can use the system's current directory instead of receiving it as input* seem to contradict each other.

Comment: Do we have to deal with symlinks? *Can* we if it's shorter.

Comment: @Dennis The absolute path (input 1) may refer to a non-existent file, while the current directory (input 2) is always valid. I guess I'll add the latter to the list of possible assumptions.

Comment: Regarding symlinks - I don't want to decide either way. If there are symlinks, any behavior is acceptable.

Comment: Do the inputs need to be strings?

Comment: Can we make any assumptions on the current directory content ? E.g. to assume it will be empty ?

Comment: @Tutleman I think anything else than strings would be too cheesy. However, if the "get current directory" function returns something other than string (some kind of "filesystem path object"), you can use this format for current directory.

Comment: @zeppelin Of course, no!

Comment: I now want someone to write a program that anytime someone uses an absolute path that could be shorter, echos to the command line, `"You know...you could have typed this [short path] instead."` Just because computers can always be just a little bit more passive-aggressive.

Comment: This is missing some critical test cases:  `/home/test /home/user/mydir/myfile /home/test` and `/a/b /a/b/d/e /a/b`

Comment: What do you mean by shorter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 32 bytes

```julia
!,~=relpath,endof
t->~t<~!t?t:!t
```

This uses the current working directory as base and cannot be tested on TIO at the moment.

#### Example run

**Warning:** This will alter your file system.

```julia
$ sudo julia --quiet
julia> function test(target,base)
       mkpath(base)
       cd(base)
       shorten(target)
       end
test (generic function with 1 method)
julia> !,~=relpath,endof
(relpath,endof)

julia> shorten = t->~t<~!t?t:!t
(::#1) (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test("/home/user/mydir/myfile","/home/user")
"mydir/myfile"

julia> test("/var/users/admin/secret/passwd","/var/users/joe/hack")
"../../admin/secret/passwd"

julia> test("/home/user/myfile","/tmp/someplace")
"/home/user/myfile"

julia> test("/dir1/dir2","/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4")
"../.."

julia> test("/dir1/dir2","/dir1/dir2")
"."
```

### Alternate version, 35 bytes (dyadic)

```julia
^,~=relpath,endof
t-b=~t<~t^b?t:t^b
```

This takes the base directory as input, so it can be tested without modifying the file system.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#fY3LCsIwEEXX9itKVgotg4@VWPwQsTBtRhpN0pCMipv@em1asOLCzYHLPTO3L7Ou8KQdcpORle0l4bwqOj50XFZH3g/sDbql88qytll6ShYCmtYQ3AN5MC@pIi9Kk0jz9KsT0XygH0MAlEZZCFR7YnAYwlNOB7NybQkarG/id2P@zsZBGBqnsabRG/bXEZtJ@MSIbcTuryaS86p/Aw)

Comment: Redefining `Base.-` errors unless explicitly imported, no?

Comment: In 0.5, it may error, but only if you use `-` before redefining it. In 0.4, it prints a warning whether you use it before the redefinition or not.

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>107</s> 106 bytes

Takes the absolute path `a` and the current path `c` in currying syntax `(a)(c)`.

```js
a=>c=>(A=a.split`/`,s='',c.split`/`.map(d=>!s&A[0]==d?A.shift():s+='../'),s+=A.join`/`)[a.length]?a:s||'.'
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>c=>(A=a.split`/`,s='',c.split`/`.map(d=>!s&A[0]==d?A.shift():s+='../'),s+=A.join`/`)[a.length]?a:s||'.'

console.log(f
  ('/home/user/mydir/myfile')
  ('/home/user')
);

console.log(f
  ('/var/users/admin/secret/passwd')
  ('/var/users/joe/hack')
);

console.log(f
  ('/home/user/myfile')
  ('/tmp/someplace')
);

console.log(f
  ('/dir1/dir2')
  ('/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4')
);

console.log(f
  ('/dir1/dir2')
  ('/dir1/dir2')
);
```

Comment: A very nice trick with `[a.length]` ! May I borrow it to improve my Node.js answer ?

Comment: @zeppelin Sure. Go for it!

Answer (score 8):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>85</s> <s>83</s> 82 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @MartinEnder*

```
^(..+)(.*;)\1
%$2
(%?)(.*);(.*)
$1$3;$2
\w+(?=.*;)
..
%;/

;
/
.*//
/
%/?|/$

^$
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#bY3BDoIwEETv8x1tUiDpBvDWGI7@BCE2UAMKQihKTPx3bPGAGi9vd2Y2s1wcjkshpIwCIUMV5DE4SyB45nWgPMBilirn5nMksr0/g5TgigAFggyJ3OCUPYkBBYNcFqr7ztDNmpG6R9V4nprWqM3HT7Aq0F2Pa2xJV11zJWvK0Uw0aGvnSn3E595QrcsLvl69u6ZuIOvcodWlAbni2CNR2@qReuz@5y8)

Answer (score 5):

## ES6 (Node.js REPL), <del>56</del>, <del>54</del>, <del>46</del>, 45 bytes

- Use empty string, instead of "." to denote the current directory (on input), -1 byte
- Borrowed the `[f.length]` trick from @Arnauld's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117038/61904), -6 bytes
- Use the current directory instead of an explicit directory parameter, -2 bytes
- Removed superfluous parentheses, -2 bytes

**Golfed**

```js
f=>(r=path.relative("",f))[f.length]?f:r||"."
```

**Test**

```
> F=f=>(r=path.relative("",f))[f.length]?f:r||"."
[Function: F]

> F("/home/user/mydir/myfile")
'mydir/myfile'

> F("/var/users/admin/secret/passwd")
'../../admin/secret/passwd'

> F("/home/user/myfile")
'/home/user/myfile'

> F("/dir1/dir2")
'../..'

> F("/dir1/dir2")
'.'
```

Comment: Do we not allow node.js functions?

Comment: @Downgoat Javascript lambdas are widely accepted, as a form of answer, so I don't see why Node.js should be handled differently.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>135</s> 144 bytes

```py
i=0
a,c=input()
b,d=a.split('/')*(a!=c),c.split('/')
while b[:i+1]==d[:i+1]:i+=1
print'.'[i:]or min('/'.join(['..']*len(d[i:])+b[i:]),a,key=len)
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#dVDLbsMgELzzFelp7QSxdZtTJL7E8mENVCbxAwFJlK93gFaNVamX2dmZWe1qVyvfGXEl7eyusapZz7UkEdxoYwUI9b6iN6lqrjYauw92NLu@PdlD00mpv0kC2TDn7RxBQGtP3eJ3k53zjDgvibQgBHT70cyVzn596EvhxC/mIZNerysgYQ@8FNRogAEOy2QwmhCzXpprMB6nh7YZv9I5v7Efp2gpHSeHIeluJFVCaaTJ8JHdV/Ovk@Ezw/Hvis3y7Vk5diNfeEDS6QUYjPImoqMQ7jqnX4HzYnAgdYEn)

Kind of long, but I wanted to do a solution without built-in path functions.

**Edit:** 9 bytes added to account for test case provided by Nathan Merrill

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) + realpath, 58 bytes

```
r=`realpath -m --relative-to=$*`
(($#2<$#r))&&r=$2
echo $r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/zsh#dU9Na8MwDL3rVwjq9QsSkWynshz3B3beoSZWibckNrbSdr8@c5pCW@jAPEtPD72nU2NbxsDaoO39IAXc6hKMm0dukNSDD7aXA64@zp5rYbPDl/jVf3IcWtkh4grVVRlZUM1Lrn8xhmqflrVeS4NZh1kWuNVij5yJq9R2D@u1WpTvahE2m@UyVKoErhuHKoxTiEuTEvU8UuM6piFyoO7X2AkP6Qy48fDAAx11uPCRtOlsT5HrwEJex3gy9@Nvx9To@gfynNJ7poYH@9lYOk8xsb7VNT8RAKU4xQTlXTnB6wRvs90/Msj/AA)

#### Bash version, 62 bytes

```sh
r=`realpath -m --relative-to=$*`
((${#2}<${#r}))&&r=$2
echo $r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#dU9Na8MwDL3rVwjm9WOQiGQ7leW4P7DzDjWxSrwlsbGVdmP0t2dOU2gLHZhn6emh93RobMsYWBu0vR@kgEtdgnHzyA2SevDB9rLD5du351rYbPAxfvTvHIdWNoi4RHVWRhZU85LzX4yh2qZlrdfSYNZhlgVutdg9Z@Iq9bSF1Ur9PpTH14ThuF4vFqFSJXDdOFRhnIKcmpSq55Ea1zENkQN1P8ZOuEunwIWHGx5or8OJj6RNZ3uKXAcW8jrGg7kefzqmRtdfkOeU3j013NjPxtJ5ion1ra75jgAoxSkmKK/KCZ4neJnt/pFB/gc)

Comment: Why not post it in two different answers? Every language matters!

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3 – 53 bytes

Using `os.path`:

```
import os
lambda x:min(x,os.path.relpath(x),key=len)
```

Full program (61 bytes):

```
import os
x=input();print(min(x,os.path.relpath(x),key=len))
```

Comment: Oo, good point(s). Python's in the lead now, yay!

Comment: @anatolyg Ha, I knew I'd miss at least one test case...  All fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 204 Bytes

```
[,$l,$p]=$argv;$z=($d=array_diff_assoc)($y=($w=explode)("/",$p),$x=$w("/",$l));$m=str_pad("",3*count($z)-1,"../");$j=join("/",$r=$d($x,$y));echo$l!=$p?strlen($u=$m&&$j?"$m/$j":$m.$j)<strlen($l)?$u:$l:".";
```

[Testcases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/843f7f9de9a3cc8d9bbaeaa8b72ac5df42992f7a)

Expanded

```
[,$l,$p]=$argv;
$z=($d=array_diff_assoc)($y=($w=explode)("/",$p),$x=$w("/",$l));
$m=str_pad("",3*count($z)-1,"../");
$j=join("/",$r=$d($x,$y));
echo$l!=$p
    ?strlen($u=$m&&$j?"$m/$j":$m.$j)<strlen($l)
      ?$u
      :$l
    :".";
```

if an Output `../../` instead `of ../..` is allowed it can be shorten to 175 Bytes

```
[,$l,$p]=$argv;$z=($d=array_diff_assoc)($y=($w=explode)("/",$p),$x=$w("/",$l));echo$l!=$p?strlen($m=str_pad("",3*count($z),"../").join("/",$r=$d($x,$y)))<strlen($l)?$m:$l:".";
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# - 66 bytes

Using a .NET [builtin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and forcing to be a valid path:

```
(f,t)=>f==t?".":new Uri("/"+t).MakeRelativeUri(new Uri("/"+f))+"";
```

Where `f`,`t` and output are `string`.

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AIW2hX)