# Shortest path between two directories

Tags: code-golf, string

The challenge is to write a program which will find the shortest (least number of characters) command which will navigate to a target directory, given a starting directory, assuming a standard linux file system.

Take the following file system as an example, starting from `~`:

```
.
├── target
└── test
    └── starting
```

If the user is in `~/test/starting` and wants to navigate to `~/target`, the shortest command is `cd ~/target`.

However, if the user is in `~/test/starting` and wants to navigate to `~/test`, the shortest command is `cd ..`

If the user wants to navigate to `~`, the shortest command is `cd ~`.

If the user wants to navigate to `/etc`, the shortest command is `cd /etc`.

**INPUT**

The input is two strings; the starting directory and the target directory. For example:
`/etc/kernel` and `/opt`.
The method and order these are input is up to you. (eg: array, list, arguments, input, etc)

**OUTPUT**

Print or return the shortest command which navigates to the target directory.

**SCORING**

Standard code golf rules.

**Some example test cases**

Input format is `starting` `target`

> Input: `~/a/b/c` `~/a/z`
>
> Output: `cd ~/a/z`

> Input: `~/apple/banana/carrot` `~/apple/banana/z`
>
> Output: `cd ../z`

> Input: `~/apple/banana/carrot` `/test`
>
> Output: `cd /test`

> Input: `/a/b` `/a/b/c`
>
> Output: `cd c`

> Input: `/a/b` `/a/b`
>
> Output: `cd .`

**CLARIFICATIONS**

- `~` is equivalent to `/home/golfer`
- Assume that inputs are already minimal. For example, you would not get `/home/golfer/a` as an input, and would instead get `~/a`
- The only aliases you need to worry about are `/` and `~`
- Shortest path from `~` to `/home` is `..`
- @loopywalt has pointed out that `cd` with no argument will navigate to `~`. This behaviour will be ignored, so please assume that an argument must always be specified.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! A few questions: 1. do we have to handle symlinks and/or hardlinks? 2. do we need to include `cd` in the output? It seems like clutter that doesn't really add any complexity 3. can we assume things like trailing `/`s for directories, `/home/...` instead of `~`, etc.?

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms
1. No
2. Yes
3. Not sure exactly what you mean by this. As long as the command will run and navigate to the directory it is ok.

Thanks for the welcome!

Comment: In the interest of self-containedness, it should probably be specified in the challenge body that (I assume) `~` is equivalent to some `/home/unnamed-user`, and that the shortest path from `~` to `/home` is (I assume) `..`. Alternatively, in the interest of simplicity, you could remove `~` entirely.

Comment: @UnrelatedString thanks, I have updated the clarifications.

Comment: On my box the shortest way to `~` is actually just `cd` without argument. Not sure whether that is site specific or true in general.

Comment: @loopywalt seems like if `HOME` is defined then [it will navigate to it by default if no argument is specified](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cd.1p.html).

Will update question.

Edit: actually I'm going to leave it as is just so that if people have started on a solution it doesn't break it.

Comment: @Arnauld thanks, have removed conflict. I don't think there will be many situations where it matters but worth fixing. Thanks!

Comment: Can we assume the inputs only contain lowercase letters, `/` and `~`? If not, what characters can it contain, and can there be spaces within paths?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen you can assume paths will have no spaces and directories will contains only A-Z, a-z and 0-9

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/117007/58563)

Comment: Are the input paths guaranteed to be absolute ones, starting with either `/` or `~`?

Comment: @loopywalt: `cd` is a shell built-in, so in theory it depends on the shell.  But `cd` using $HOME (the same env var it uses to expand `~`) is POSIX standard behaviour, and started very early with the original Unix Bourne Shell (`sh`) which inspired ksh / bash / zsh, etc.  According to  
Stéphane Chazelas
 on [Why does cd default to ~?](//unix.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/109582), csh/tcsh and all the "exotic" shells like fish and rc do this too, because it's what people are used to.  (Apparently DOS `cmd` doesn't, but even Windows Powershell does return to your home dir when you `cd`. )

Comment: @Arnauld regarding absolute paths, yes that is guaranteed.

Comment: `~` may not be `/home/UserID` in MacOS (which is POSIX-compliant, unlike some Linux distros), `~` is usually `/Users/UserID` but can be changed.

Comment: Phrasing this in terms of `cd` is, once again, confusing and pointless, and it's continuing to cause confusion in answers. Can you _please_ remove that part?

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>60</s> 56 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ëi'.ë'~’/€¨/’:'/©δ¡ζ.γË}¦˜2ôøðδK`®ýsg…../×ì®Ü}Iθ)éн…cd ì
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@JonathanAllan*

Inputs as a pair.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cHemut7h1ep1jxpm6j9qWnNohT6QZaWuf2jluS2HFp7bpndu8@Hu2kPLTs8xOrzl8I7DG85t8U44tO7w3uL0Rw3L9PT0D08/vAbIn1PreW6H5uGVF/YChZNTFA6v@f8/WqlOP7GgICdVPykxDwj1kxOLivJLlHTQxauUYgE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/8Pdmep6h1er16k/alpzaIW6/qGVeod3WB1ad27LoYXntumd23y4u/bQstNzjA5vObzj8IZzW7wTDq07vLc4/VHDMj09/cPTD68B8ufUVp7boXl45YW9QOHkFIXDa/7r/I@OVqrTL0ktLtEvLkksKsnMS1fSAYkkFqWnlijF6ijgkAeKIMuCBNH4@qklyTChRP0k/WSwxkT9KrhgQUFOqn5SYh4Q6icnFhXll0CUIIsTUI3kEJAlIBGIXehCUGNAvIz83FQ0rn5osGuQoZExVFtZakZmMtA2oDX6xQX5RSXFIFZKfn6Rfk5@cjZIF7KSkqLS5GwkaTSz0/Nz0pRiYwE).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ëi              # If both paths in the (implicit) input-pair are the same:
  '.           '#  Push "."
 ë              # Else:
  '~      :    '#  In the strings of the (implicit) input-pair, replace all "~"
    ’/€¨/’      #  with dictionary string "/home/"
  '/©          '#  Push "/", and save it in variable `®` (without popping)
     δ          #  Map over the pair, with "/" as argument:
      ¡         #   Split the paths in the strings by this "/"
  ζ.γË}¦˜2ôøðδK #  Remove the matching path-prefixes:
  ζ             #   Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns,
                #   using a " " as filler-character if the paths are of unequal length
   .γ }         #   Then group the pairs by:
     Ë          #    Check if the two values in the pair are the same
      }¦        #   After the group-by: remove the first group
        ˜       #   Flatten it to a single list
         2ô     #   Split it back into pairs
           ø    #   Zip/transpose these pairs back
             δ  #   Map over each inner list:
            ð K #    Remove all spaces
  `             #  Pop and push both lists separated to the stack
   ®ý           #  Join the second list with "/" delimiter
   s            #  Swap so the first list is at the top of the stack
    g           #  Pop and push its length
     …../×      #  Pop this length, and repeat string "../" that many times
   ì            #  Prepend it in front of the other string
    ®Ü          #  And trim a potentially trailing "/"
 }              # Close the if-else statement
  Iθ            # Push the second string of the input-pair
)               # Wrap all values on the stack into a list
 é              # Sort it by length
  н             # Pop and leave just the first/shortest one
   …cd ì        # Prepend "cd " in front of it
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `’/€¨/’` is `"/home/"`.

Comment: Perhaps "you would not get `/home/golfer/a` as an input, and would instead get `~/a`" allows you to use something shorter than `Šˆer`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks! Just removing it and using `/home/` is indeed a lot shorter. :)

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 101 bytes

Expects `[ current_dir, target_dir ]`.

```javascript
a=>'cd '+((s=require('path').relative(...a.map(s=>(q=s).replace(/~/,'/home/@')))||".")[q.length]?q:s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldHNbgIhEAfwe5@C7AVIdebeZG3fw3gYcXTXsAsL1IMxvvp2vzRNtNsWLiQz/OAPRzpRNKH0aVm7Hbf7vKV8Jc1OyFelYh64@SwDK@kpFVJDYEupPLECAIKKfNezUk0e@5K3ZFjhFRcSC1cxfkit9eWSQabXDViuD6nYvDdvUbfG1dFZBusOaq/WIrsi4RZNthiX50xstBY/DkTRXXLofHlmeW8Zt1R3Ew2F4NIkfy9Mh4wWwL8oTBzTwyVHaqg9Wn3CYeuYdD7gzTLzzq/KzYEn2Qak/6k/KHdnFsKjY0yVnwXv7z01t18)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 66 bytes

Expects `(current_dir)(target_dir)`.

Assumes a *nix system where `~` redirects to `/home/some_user`. On TIO, `~` is `/home/runner/~`. So this may fail because of that.

```javascript
a=>b=>'cd '+((s=require('path').relative(a,b)||".")[b.length]?b:s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc9LDsIgEAbgvado2ABRYW/SehDjYqDThyGlAnZhGq9eax@JqbFG2JDM8M38F2jAa1fWYV/ZFLss7iBOVJxQnUZ0y5iPHV5vpUNGawgF5cKhgVA2yGCneNsSQfhJCYNVHorzUR0877StvDUojM1ZxshDglRSEz4@74Tz6OuRMupHD32bT6euDUoFVX@lBudsmNT3wjBgdIT4g5EBfVgsNzJDZem8Ug3fpnQroWZHrxk/hNkQ3RM)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 81 bytes

```python
lambda p:'cd '+min(relpath(*map(expanduser,p)),p[0],key=len)
from os.path import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY3LCsIwEEX3/YrsktRgBHdCv6TtYtpOaTGPIY1gXfjr0VYEFQWZxQz3nOHSHAfv9qkvqmTANh0wOvC2Y3xjRycCGoI4iNwCCTwTuO40YVAkpaJyV6sjzoVBJ7M@eMv8tF10NlryIeaJwuii6EXJrxr0hat1N7rltZTZGyUyqBtw93mKr1ELIfj48aYjTvFf99Gr1uML@0EGb3FpWPJ0Aw)

This utilizes the `os.path.relpath` function to get a relative path. The shortest path command is either the relative path or the absolute path, whichever is shorter, so the code just checks which using `min`. `expanduser` is used to expand the `~` directory to the user's home directory, which doesn't have to be `home/golfer` to meet the requirements. This is necessary to handle cases with `~` in the path name.

Comment: Uh I noticed that someone posted a 69 byte answer a few minutes before me in python. Sorry I didn't see that one before I answered.

Comment: This seems to output `cd ../..` instead of `cd ..` for `['/home','~']`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ok, it should work now. Thanks for noticing that!

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 99 bytes

```
$
¶$%`
¶
/¶
m`^~(?=/.*¶)
/home/golfer
^(.*/)(.*¶)\1
$2
\G.*?/
../
1`¶

/¶
¶
O#$`
$.&
1G`
^$
.
^
cd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYw9CsMwDIX3dwpDneJksEj3kjFjh67B2EndH8gfrqcOOVYOkIu5TjoUCkXSk9CTPmf9ozchEWfNAscy80RHBcXqtJpEcSSZLXMKug@dpdvQXq2DEjKjVGxOlYMfUJUyKwhSEnIdnzdCzNOOa3C5R15qKA4JhebCQpjIUE0NW/sLUcextVSbPgY1xrnBs5/tvzPy9umx8tgH@p3f) Takes input on separate lines but link is to test suite that splits on space for convenience. Explanation:

```
$
¶$%`
```

Duplicate the last (to) line.

```
¶
/¶
```

Append `/` to the first two (original from and to) lines.

```
m`^~(?=/.*¶)
/home/golfer
```

Expand any leading `~` on the first two lines.

```
^(.*/)(.*¶)\1
$2
```

Remove any common prefix (ending in `/`) on the first two lines.

```
\G.*?/
../
```

Change any remaining "from" directories to `..`.

```
1`¶
```

Join those `..`s with the remaining "to" directories.

```
/¶
¶
```

Remove the trailing `/`.

```
O#$`
$.&
```

Sort numerically by length.

```
1G`
```

Take the first i.e. shortest string.

```
^$
.
```

If it's the empty string then replace it with `.`.

```
^
cd
```

Prefix `cd`  to the string.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 66 bytes

```cs
(a,b,c)=>"cd "+((c=Path.GetRelativePath(a,b)).Length<b.Length?c:b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZAxb8IwEIV3fsXJky3SeA8ENrpkqFi6sNjHAZYiE9lHhRj46ykxCGVAuKo8@J38/L7Tw/iB0fWrk8d55OD8voDX9wJ2UEMvTWELVPVC4BbEVEqsvwwfyk/iNbWG3Q8N82BTqmzI7/kwtw@xxMqqfjaZfAfH1DhPUgAEiqeWKxAwhZ0UV2201SgKSPIyCKHUbPyJzh0h07aC2xbJtfF3Xz6861rS1vjb0WhCOPIDNX7IU8syQf8N1EyRs5Tk2njIcobSUuyzvLe5@IfVx5H5OlJg/ws)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 87 bytes

```python
lambda t,s:"cd "+[t,r:=relpath(t:=expanduser(t),s)][len(r)<len(t)];from os.path import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XYxNCsIwFIT3niJklWg0W6n2Al7ARe0ibRNayB8vr6AuvIibguidvI0tFRcyi4GP-eb-ihdsgx8eJj89ezTr7ftolasaRVCkjNYNoasCBWQ5aBsVtgyzXJ-j8k2fNDDkIvGysNoz4PupkJc7A8GRkDaTQDoXA-Dye3-I0HlkhtGbVDFaLSvlx8grFf-oVgABKeeLnyTb4PS0HOn8OAxzfwA)

Expects `target, start`.

Comment: This seems to output `cd /home` instead of `cd ..` for `f("/home","~")`