# Print multiplication tables by input

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

In this challenge you've to print multiplication tables by input, Here are some examples:

```
Input: 2 

Output: 
0 2  4 6 8  10  12  14  16  18  20

Input: 20

Output: 20 40 60 80 100 120 140 160 180 200
```

## Rules

1. The shortest code in bytes wins.
2. This challenge is a code-golf, It follows code-golf general rules ([code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf))
3. If, just if, your code can't print number, you can use letters, Here is an example:

   Input: B

   Output: B D F H J L N P R T
4. You can choose to start from 0 or your number (like 20). You can choose if put spaces or don't. The challenge is free, just take an input and print multiplication tables.
5. Your output must list the first 10 members of the times table for the given number. You may leave out 0*n.

Comment: Your first example has multiples from 0 to 10, the second from 1 to 10. Can we choose either of these or is one of them a typo? Also, does output have to be space-separated or can we use other list-formats? (If only spaces, the number of spaces is a bit random in your example.)

Comment: You can choose to start from 0 or your number (like 20). You can choose if put spaces or don't. The challenge is free, just take an input and print multiplication tables.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice to see a pretty simply challenge, since we don't have these enough, although in the future I would add some more information. Like: From the test cases it seems we only need to output 10 numbers, but I don't see this specified. Do we need to support negative input? Why are there two spaces between 2 and 4? Why does the first test case have the 0 in it's output (making it 11 output numbers instead of 10). etc. etc. Also, the [Sandbox for proposed challenges is a good place to post first to perfect the challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/52210)

Comment: Under rule 3, what should the output for `C` be? How about `Z`?

Comment: What exactly is the output, the normal rules tend to allow a function to return its output as a list rather than printing them to STDOUT.

Answer (score 10):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 4 bytes

```
10:*
```

Breakdown:

```
        % Implicit input
10:     % Create a list from 1 2 ... 10
   *    % Multiply list by input
        % Implicit output
```

**[Try it online](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MTA6Kg&input=NQ)**

Answer (score 10):

## C#, <s>105</s> <s>96</s> <s>67</s> 56 bytes

Now that I know how lambda's work in C#, here is an update to my first answer:

```
n=>{for(int i=0;i++<10;)System.Console.Write(i*n+" ");};
```

Saves 11 bytes.

---

First post, please forgive me for anything I've done wrong.  Also, feel free to give me golfing tips, as I haven't really tried it before!

```
void c(int n){for(int i=0;i++<10;){System.Console.Write(i*n+" ");}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
void c(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i++ < 10 ; )
    {
        System.Console.Write(i*n+" ");
    }
}
```

Thank you Jonathan Allan, can't add comments yet.
And thank you Kevin Cruijssen.  I assumed I had to always include the entire program unless the question specified that snippets were allowed.  Would I also be able to leave out the System. call to print to console in this case, or are using/imports required then?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can remove the class, only the main function is required by golfing rules :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Not only that, but by those same rules you can also just make a separate method without `Main` altogether. I.e. `void f(int n){for(int i=0;i++<10;){System.Console.Write(i*n+" ");}}` And indeed, welcome to PPCG!

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/173/39436

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁵R×
```

Test it at [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oG1UsOX&input=&args=Mw)
Or first 256 cases, nicely aligned, also at [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oG1UsOXCuKBucOH4oKsRw&input=&args=)

How?

```
⁵R× - main link takes one argument, n
⁵   - literal 10
 R  - range [1,2,...,10]
  × - multiply by input (implicit vectorization)
```

Comment: I'd love to learn Jelly but half the commands don't render for me, so it'd be useless :D

Comment: @BetaDecay I can't type most of them and they don't render for me in any text editor or on my cmd line :( - they render fine in Firefox on my Windows 7 machine though.

Comment: You and Emigma are winning.

Comment: @BetaDecay - It could help you to [download](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Download) and (re)install DejaVu Sans Mono font (I can now see *almost* every character in notepad++ and TIO through Firefox is now using it too and displaying every character still)

Comment: Exactly what I thought of, +1.

Answer (score 8):

### Clojure, 70 <s>80</s> bytes

This is my first post on CG, I hope the input is OK:

**70 bytes**

```
(defn -main[& a](println(map #(* %(read-string(first a)))(range 10))))
```

**80 bytes**

```
(defn -main[& a](let[n(read-string(first a))](println(map #(* % n)(range 10)))))
```

The program will read a number as a stdin argument and display the result:

### Output

```
lein run 10
(0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90)
```

Comment: Welcome! That's a great first answer!

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
TL*
```

**Explanation**

```
T    # literal predefined  as 10
 L   # 1-based range: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  *  # multiply with input
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=VEwq&input=MjA)

Comment: You and Jonathan Allan are winning

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, 19 bytes

Includes +1 for `-n`

Run with the input on STDIN:

```
perl -M5.1010 -n table.pl <<< 8
```

`table.pl`:

```
say$_*$`for/$/..10
```

Comment: You probably meant `-n` ? or did I miss something?

Comment: @Dada: right, conflated it with another version. Fixed

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 16 bytes

```
(<$>[1..10]).(*)
```

Usage example: `(<$>[1..10]).(*) $ 4` -> `[4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40]`.

Pointfree version of: `f n = map (n*) [1..10]`.

Comment: What does `<$>` do?

Comment: @Cyoce: `<$>` is an infix version of `fmap` (or `map` when used with a list), i.e. it applied the function given as it's 1st argument to every element of the list. `func <$> list`= `fmap func list`= `map func list`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jellyfish](http://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 8 bytes

```
p*r11
 i
```

[Try it online!](http://jellyfish.tryitonline.net/#code=cCpyMTEKIGk&input=MjA)

Quite simple: `r11` gives the list `[0, 1, ..., 9, 10]`, `i` reads the input, `*` multiplies them and `p` prints the resulting list.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 34 bytes

(34 bytes)

```
for(;$i++<10;)echo$i*$argv[1].' ';
```

(34 bytes)

```
for(;++$i%11;)echo$i*$argv[1].' ';
```

(34 bytes)

```
while($i++<10)echo$i*$argv[1].' ';
```

(35 bytes)

```
for(;$i++<10;)echo' '.$a+=$argv[1];
```

(<s>41</s> 40 bytes)

```
<?=join(' ',range(0,10*$a=$argv[1],$a));
```

```
<?=join(' ',range($a=$argv[1],10*$a,$a));
```

(44 bytes)

```
foreach(range(1,10)as$i)echo$i*$argv[1].' ';
```

Comment: The one using `range()` with `$step` can be shorter if you start it from 0: `<?=join(' ',range(0,10*$a=$argv[1],$a));`.

Comment: The rule allowing to start from 0 was not set when I did it, but you're right; I update this one.

Answer (score 4):

## R, 11 bytes

```
scan()*0:10
```

30 char.

Answer (score 4):

## J, 8 bytes

```
(i.10)&*
```

This is the range from `0` to `9` inclusive (`i.10`) *bonded* (`&`) wit the multiplication function (`*`). This starts at zero.

### Test cases

```
   k =: (i.10)&*
   k 2
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18
   k 10
0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
   k"0 i.10
0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18
0 3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27
0 4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36
0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45
0 6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54
0 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63
0 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72
0 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3, <s>52</s> <s>33</s> 30 bytes

```
lambda n:list(range(0,11*n,n))
```

3 bytes saved thanks to @manatwork

Formatting the output is visibly not necessary

Comment: Borrow from my shell answer: `lambda n:" ".join(map(str,range(0,n*11,n)))`

Comment: @manatwork I use Python 3

Comment: You use Python 3 but you can save 6 bytes by using Python 2: `lambda n:range(0,11*n,n)`

Comment: Author AFK for a year. [new answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225069/103702) 26 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Zsh, 19 characters

```zsh
echo {0..${1}0..$1}
```

Sample run:
(This is the interactive way to run it, equivalent with `zsh scriptfile.sh 20`.)

```
~ % set -- 20          

~ % echo {0..${1}0..$1}
0 20 40 60 80 100 120 140 160 180 200
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, <s>61</s> 57 bytes

```
void c(int n){for(int i=0;i++<10;)System.out.print(i*n);}
```

**Ungolfed & test cases:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/yozUSX)

```
class M{
  static void c(int n){
    for(int i = 0; i++ < 10; ){
      System.out.print(i*n);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    c(2);
    System.out.println();
    c(20);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2468101214161820
20406080100120140160180200
```

Comment: Spaces are optional, System.out.print(i*n); would save 4 bytes

Comment: @CameronD17 Ah, that rule has been added after I made this answer, but thanks for mentioning. I've removed it.

Answer (score 3):

### Mata, <strike>15</strike> 29 Bytes

```
args i
mata
A=1..10
B=`i'*A
B
```

Mata is the matrix programming language in the Stata commercial statistics package. Code creates a matrix, multiplies by the input (2 in this case) and the outputs the new matrix

### Output

```
        1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    +---------------------------------------------------+
  1 |   2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20  |
    +---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How is it taking input? It needs to be reusable too.

Comment: OK, have edited to clarify receipt of input

Answer (score 3):

## Pure Bash, 18

```
echo $[{0..10}*$1]
```

The input is taken as a command-line parameter.

Comment: Good & great ^_^

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
f=(x,i=11)=>--i&&f(x,i)+" "+x*i
```

It's a recursive solution.

Answer (score 3):

### Stata, 46 bytes

```
args i
set obs `i'
gen x=_n
gen y=x*`i'
list y
```

### Output

For i=15

```
    +-----+
    |   y |
    |-----|
 1. |  15 |
 2. |  30 |
 3. |  45 |
 4. |  60 |
 5. |  75 |
    |-----|
 6. |  90 |
 7. | 105 |
 8. | 120 |
 9. | 135 |
 10.| 150 |
    |-----|
 11.| 165 |
 12.| 180 |
 13.| 195 |
 14.| 210 |
 15.| 225 |
```

Comment: There are a few extra shorthands you can use here: ob for obs, g for gen, and l for list. Also, is it possible to have x be _n*`i' instead of using two variables?
I'd never seen args before in STATA. Thanks for showing me something new!

Answer (score 3):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org), 20 bytes

```
n->(|>11).map(n&(*))
```

Yay for functional \o/

I don't think this needs explanation but if you'd like to me add one just ask :)

Comment: I should learn Cheddar. And what does `n&(*)` do? I'm assuming `(*)` means the same thing it means I'm haskell, but what does `&` do in that context?

Comment: @Cyoce it's  [bonding](https://docs.cheddar.vihan.org/Functional%20Operations/Functional%20Bonding.html)

Answer (score 3):

**T-SQL 61 bytes**

Replace n with the number for which table needs to be populated. [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/536152)

```
SELECT TOP 11 number*n FROM master..spt_values WHERE type='P'
```

spt_value is a undocumented table in SQL Server, you can read more about this table in

- [Purpose and meaning of spt_values table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-me)
- [What does Spt_value means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229392/what-does-from-master-spt-values-mean)

I hope someone will come up with better TSQL solution.

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 24 bytes

```
(n:Int)=>0 to 10 map(n*)
```

Explanation:

```
(n:Int)=> //define an anonymous function
  0 to 10 //create a range from 0 to 10
  map(n*) //multiply each element by the input
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 12 bytes

```
@(x)x*[1:10]
```

Not really much to it. An anonymous function that takes `x` as input and multiplies it by the vector `[1:10]`. Displays as `ans = 2  4  6 ..`. Also works in Octave.

**[Try it online](https://ideone.com/MrtnwH).**

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 5 bytes

```
TSQm*
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=TSQm%2a&input=2)

Or `TQm*` if allowed to do numbers `0-9` rather than `1-10`

Or `TL*` if we're going non-competitive.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
,10y:[?]z:*a
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=LDEweTpbP116Oiph&input=MjA&args=Wg&debug=on)

I need to implement that `I * [A, B, C] = [I*A, I*B, I*C]`…

#### Explanation

```
,10y            The range [0, 1, …, 10]
    :[?]z       The list [[0, Input], [1, Input], …, [10, Input]]
         :*a    The list [0*Input, 1*Input, …, 10*Input]
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 42 bytes

```
function f(a){for(i=0;i<11;i++)alert(i*a)}
```

Comment: I don't know JS very well, can you move the increment into the test portion of the for?

Comment: I edited it. It's ok now.

Comment: It alerts now with alert().

Comment: It was alerting for me without alert: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert2) - I take that back, need to click "run" not just "try" to reload

Comment: @JonathanAllan What?

Comment: ...`for(i=0;i++<10;)` works too though, for the 1*, 2*, ... option

Comment: ES6 syntax: `f=a=>{for(i=0;i++<10;)alert(i*a)}` (33 characters)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainf***](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 84 bytes

```
,[>+>++>+++>++++>+++++>++++++>+++++++>++++++++>+++++++++>++++++++++<<<<<<<<<<-]>[.>]
```

Expects input as a single byte (as BF can only operate on numbers up to 255) and returns results as single bytes.  Some values may look like ASCII, but they should not be treated as such; look at the decimal representation of the returned bytes.

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LFs-Kz4rKz4rKys-KysrKz4rKysrKz4rKysrKys-KysrKysrKz4rKysrKysrKz4rKysrKysrKys-KysrKysrKysrKzw8PDw8PDw8PDwtXT5bLj5d&input=QQ&debug=on)

Comment: You can save 5 bytes by doing >,[>+>++>+++>++++>+++++>++++++>+++++++>++++++++>+++++++++>++++++++++[<]>-]>[.>]

Comment: @Jeff Unfortunately, that breaks any input that's higher than 25 because the byte will overflow, resetting to 0.  The overflow `0`s get matched by `[<]`, which makes the entire process loop infinitely.

Comment: Right, but overflowing bytes result in incorrect outputs with your code anyway, don't they?

Comment: @Jeff They're correct outputs, they're just operating in mod 255.

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, <strike>41</strike> 35 bytes

Usage `scala multiplicationtable.scala <input>`

Code

```
print(1 to 10 map(args(0).toInt*))
```

Comment: You can drop the dots and some parentheses: `1 to 10 map(_*args(0).toInt)map print`

Answer (score 2):

## Racket 31 bytes

```
(λ(n)(for/list((i 11))(* n i)))
```

Saved 7 bytes using suggestion by @StevenH "define(f n)"  replaced by "λ(n)".

Testing:

```
(f 2)
'(0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20)

(f 20)
'(0 20 40 60 80 100 120 140 160 180 200)

(f 7)
'(0 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70)

(f 19)
'(0 19 38 57 76 95 114 133 152 171 190)
```

Comment: You can use a lambda `λ` to save 6 bytes: `(λ(n)(for/list((i 11))(* n i)))`

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, 23 bytes

```
param($n)1..10|%{$_*$n}
```

Takes input via command-line argument, loops over the range `1` to `10`, each loop placing that number `*$n` on the pipeline. Output via implicit `Write-Output` at end of program execution results in newline separated values.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\multiplication-table.ps1 2
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\multiplication-table.ps1 20
20
40
60
80
100
120
140
160
180
200
```

Answer (score 2):

## C89, 44 bytes

```
k;main(n){for(k=n*11;k-=n;)printf("%d ",k);}
```

#### Ungolfed:

```
k;
main(n)
{
    for (k=n*11 ; k-=n ;)
        printf("%d ", k);
}
```

#### Compile and run with (input 4)

```
gcc -ansi main.c && ./a.out 2 3 4
```

#### Output

```
40 36 32 28 24 20 16 12 8 4
```

#### Test it

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b16e8684c36b850)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

## **Groovy (39 bytes for dynamic, 21 for static):**

### Dynamic (39 bytes)

```
{a,b,c->(a..b).collect{it*c}}(1,10,2)​
```

- a is the starting point of the table
- b is the ending point of the table.
- c is the factor

(1, 10, 2) would print:

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

Try it here:
https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/5194081252671488

---

### Partial Dynamic (29 bytes)

```
{n->(1..10).collect{it*n}}(2)
```

Try it here: {same website, I can't post 3 links}/5080994763767808

---

### Static (21 bytes)

```
(1..10).collect{it*2}
```

Try it here: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5110807876599808

---

### Original Post Mistakes

Edited because someone pointed out I had made mistakes, original version was:

```
def x(a,b,c){[a..b].each{println it*c}}
```

Mistakes were:

> - Not including the call to the closure in the byte-count.
> - [a..b] instead of (a..b).

Comment: Without dynamic input's it is:
`def x(c){[1..10].each{println it*c}}`

Comment: I'm afraid if your code expects a value required to work, other then the specified input, that has to be included in the length count. So better go with the hardcoded 1..10 range. By the way, anonymous functions/procs/lambdas/closures are acceptable: `{c->(1..10).each{println it*c}}` http://pastebin.com/FWBtSy77 Oh, could you specify your Groovy version? In 2.4.5 your code produces strange output: http://pastebin.com/6s0yeUx8

Comment: As there are some other solutions that output the language's native list representation, here it is in Groovy: `{print((1..10)*.multiply(it))}`.

Comment: I updated it based on your comments, and I actually did make some mistakes in the initial posting as well.

Comment: Groovy version didn't matter it was the [1..10] instead of using (1..10), which made it a 2D array which made it completely different haha.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES6), <strike>34</strike> 31 bytes

```
a=>{for(i=0;i<11;)alert(++i*a)}
(a)=>{for(i=0;i<11;++i)alert(i*a)}
```

Saved 3 bytes thanks to grizzly.

Comment: At the very least you don't need the parentheses around the `a`, but I think it's also possible to be creative as to the position of the `++`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak) <s>50</s> 46 bytes

[Try it online](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=PD4oKCgpKCkoKSkoe30pe30peyh7fVsoKV08KCh7fSk8Pih7fSk8Pik-KX17fQ&input=)

```
<>((()()())({}){}){({}[()]<(({})<>({})<>)>)}{}
```

### Explanation

Switch to the off stack and push 9:

```
<>((()()())({}){})
```

Decrement the nine until zero

```
{({}[()]<...>)}{}
```

Each time add the input value a copy of the top value

```
(({})<>({})<>)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 24 bytes

```
;;..I1.N-?W.;;)W@/So..*O
```

Cubix is a 2-dimensional, stack-based esolang. Cubix is different from other 2D langs in that the source code is wrapped around the outside of a cube.

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix) Note: you'll have to copy-paste the code, and there's a 50 ms delay between iterations.

### Explanation

The first thing the interpreter does is figure out the smallest cube that the code will fit onto. In this case, the edge-length is 1. Then the code is padded with no-ops `.` until all six sides are filled. Whitespace is removed before processing, so this code is identical to the above:

```
    ; ;
    . .
I 1 . N - ? W .
; ; ) W @ / S o
    . .
    * O
```

Comment: Here's a slightly shorter one using the new stack options `I.0.WrN;-!@vrW>r)*O;o`

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 5 Bytes

[Try It Online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VhT%2AN&input=20&debug=0)

```
VhT*N
```

***explanation***

```
V    for unary_range(
hT   Ten+1)
*N   Print (N *Input)
```

***Example***

```
===================== Input ======================
20
==================================================

0
20
40
60
80
100
120
140
160
180
200
```

Answer (score 2):

## [3d](https://github.com/Moonstroke/3d), 35 bytes

#### Code:

```
>#a…:>×=$v
   ;, !a#—v
     ^ ! '<
```

#### Explanation:

```
#a push 10
…  push every number in the range top..1 (=> 10..1)
:  input number
×  push product of top two of the stack
=  output as number
$  invert top two of the stack
—  pops stack and check if null
if is null:
    #a! print newline
    ,;  pops silently and exits
if not:
    ' ! print a space
... and loops back to ×
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 5 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Begins at 0× or 1× depending on `⎕IO`.

```apl
⎕×⍳10
```

`⎕` input

`×` times

`⍳10` first 10 integers

TryAPL online: [with `⎕IO←0`](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2206%u21902http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%20%u22C4%20%u2206%u21902%20%u22C4%20%u2206%D7%u237310%20%u22C4%20%u2206%u219020%20%u22C4%20%u2206%D7%u237310&run)
and
[with `⎕IO←1`](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21901%20%u22C4%20%u2206%u21902%20%u22C4%20%u2206%D7%u237310%20%u22C4%20%u2206%u219020%20%u22C4%20%u2206%D7%u237310&run)
.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 10 bytes

```perl6
{$_ X*^11}
```

### Explanation:

```perl6
{
  # the input
  $_

  # crossed using &infix:<*>
  X[*]

  # a Range from 0 to 11 excluding 11
  # ( short for ｢0 ..^ 11｣ )
  ^11
}
```

```perl6
say {$_ X*^11}(20)
# (0 20 40 60 80 100 120 140 160 180 200)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Forth, 31 bytes

Pretty simple answer. Leaves `n` on the stack.

```
: f 10 0 DO dup I 1+ * . LOOP ;
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/DXVI)

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge 93 : 24 bytes

```
&:01+*.20g1+:"9"`#@_20p#
```

Fairly straightforward. Uses **g**et and **p**ut instructions to keep track of the iterator.

Answer (score 2):

## [Sesos](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos), 12 bytes

```
~~
```

Since this contains unprintables, here is an `xxd` reversible hexdump:

```
0000000: d6cb82 06efbe 7e7ed0 ef1fcf                       ......~~....
```

The SASM that was used to compile the above SBIN is here:

```
set numin            ;Input consists of linefeed-separated integers from now on.
set numout           ;Output consists of linefeed-separated integers from now on.
get                  ;Get the input.
fwd 1                ;Go to the repeat-count cell.
add 10               ;Repeat 10 times.
jmp                  ;Enter the loop.
 sub 1                ;This is a repeat-n-times loop.
 rwd 1                ;Go to the proper cell.
 jmp                  ;Table generation method.
  sub 1                ;Value copying.
  fwd 2                ;Go to the multiple cell.
  add 1                ;Add the value.
  fwd 1                ;Go to an empty cell.
  add 1                ;Copy the original value, so that we don't lose it.
  rwd 3                ;Enable finishing check.
 jnz                  ;Check if the method is finished.
 fwd 3                ;Where the original value has been copied.
 jmp                  ;Move the value back to its original place.
  sub 1                ;Empty the cell.
  rwd 3                ;Go to the original cell.
  add 1                ;Set it to the original value.
  fwd 3                ;Enable finishing check.
 jnz                  ;Check if the moving is finished.
 rwd 1                ;Go to the multiply cell.
 put                  ;Print its value.
 rwd 1                ;Enable finishing check.
                     ;(implicit jnz) Check if execution should be terminated.
```

[Try it online!](http://sesos.tryitonline.net#code=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&input=MTE)

Output is like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 1):

## Fourier, 15 bytes

```
I~N11(i*Noi^~i)
```

Output for input `20`:

```
020406080100120140160180200
```

Since unseparated output [is allowed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32160323#32160323).

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=SX5OMTEoaSpOb2lefmkp&input=MjA)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 7 bytes

```
m*dQU11

Input: 2
Output: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Prints as a list, but can print as seen in the question with a simple modification, making it 9 bytes.

```
jdm*dQU11

Input: 20
Output: 0 20 40 60 80 100 120 140 160 180 200
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Neoscript](https://github.com/Neoscript-lang/neoscript), 16 bytes

```
{n|0:[n]:(10*n)}
```

Inspired by @manatwork answer

Answer (score 1):

## [LI](https://github.com/Steven-Hewitt/LI/blob/master/Interpreter.py), 30 bytes

```
M1iM2iM3iM4iM5iM6iM7iM8iM9iMY9
```

The lack of a working list implementation does not win me any awards today.

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](http://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 41 bytes

First time trying to use Labyrinth.  I have no idea how to take advantage of grid manipulation, so I ignored it in my answer.  There's <s>probably</s> certainly better ways to do this, but I don't know how to do it.

```
10}
  ?
: :
:::
  :
":"
"
!\{(@
"  }
":+"
```

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=MTB9CiAgPwo6IDoKOjo6CiAgOgoiOiIKIgohXHsoQAoiICB9CiI6KyI&input=NQ&debug=on)

Comment: If it's any consolation, apart from a couple of very specific use cases I also don't know how to take advantage of grid manipulation. ;)

Comment: One such use case is to start with a long piece of linear code "for free" though: http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=PDo6Ojo6Ojo6Oj99MDEKOgohXHsoQAoiICB9CiI6KyI&input=NQ&debug=on (although I'm sure there must be a way that avoids duplicating 10 times)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 24 bytes

```
lambda n:range(0,11*n,n)
```

`range()` in Python 2 returns a list, so there is no need to convert.

Comment: That one uses Python 3. This one uses Python 2. The code is shorter by 6 bytes. Therefore, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @OliverNi Yes, it is, since it uses the same method, and is the same language, just different version. The other one using `list` is just because Python 3's `range` is equivalent to Python 2's `xrange`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
UòA*UU
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=VfJBKlVV&input=Mg==)

#### How it works

```
        // Implicit: U = input integer, A = 10
Uò      // Create a range from U to
  A*U   //  10 * U,
     U  //  skipping by U each time.
        // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash on OSX, 13

```
jot 11 0 - $1
```

The input is taken as a command-line parameter.  This will also work on Linux is `jot` is installed; e.g. `sudo apt-get install athena-jot`.

Comment: Can't you use jot `11 0 -$1`?

Comment: @Rizze I don't think so - that would could down from `0` to `$1 * -1` in 11 steps

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 10 bytes

```
#Range@10&
```

`Range@10` is the list {1,2,...,10}, which is then multiplied by the input `#`.

Answer (score 1):

### C, 39 bytes

```
i;F(n){while(i<11)printf("%d ",n*i++);}
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/RGdLIV)

---

Input:

```
10
```

Output:

```
0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 44 bytes

```
$a=$argv[1];for($i=0;$i<10*$a;$i+=$a)echo$i;
```

Comment: You can remove 1 byte using `echo$i`instead of `echo$i;`.

Comment: And how you run it? Without the semicolon I get only error: http://pastebin.com/uGbRA6KA

Comment: @manatwork true, i didn't even check before editing, my bad

Answer (score 1):

## jq, 15 characters

```
range(0;.*11;.)
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq 'range(0;.*11;.)' <<< 20
0
20
40
60
80
100
120
140
160
180
200
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=range(0%3b.*11%3b.)&j=20)

Comment: Can't you use `range(0;.*11)`?

Comment: @Rizze, then step defaults to 1, so for 20 will not output 0, 20, 40, …, 200, but 0, 1, 2, …, 219.

Comment: Oh ok, Can't you just delete **.** or **;**?

Comment: Nope. `.` is kind of default variable, something like `$_` in Perl and `it` in Groovy. `;` is the parameter separator, like `,` in most programming language. To use `range()` with step, you have to pass 3 parameters and none of them can be empty.

Comment: Ah ok :) Understood

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 63 bytes

Feels a bit long...

```
$
¶10$*
+`¶(1(1+))
¶$2 $1
^.+
$*
(?<=(1+)¶.*)1
$1
.*¶

(1)+
$#1
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JArCtjEwJCoKK2DCtigxKDErKSkKwrYkMiAkMQpeLisKJCoKKD88PSgxKynCti4qKTEKJDEKLirCtgoKKDEpKwokIzE&input=MjA)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
*RQST
```

If we're allowed to print the table from `0-9`, `*RQT` would work as well.  Outputs in list `[2, 4, 6, 8,...]` form.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 62 bytes

```
void P(int x){for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){Console.WriteLine(x*i);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3:**

[The current Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92505/103702) has several flaws:

1. the author hasn't been online for a year.
2. does not count the print, and this answer, and possibly others, requires it built-in.

This answer, not counting the input `n=2` and the `print()` has 26 Bytes, which beats [the current best](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92505/103702).

Counting everything (which is much easier to compare): 36 bytes.

I suggest this to be the updating answer.

```
n=2;s=0
while s<11: print(s*n); s+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8/WyLrY1oCrPCMzJ1Wh2MbQ0EqhoCgzr0SjWCtP01qhWNvW8P9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 37 bytes

```
,<++++++++++[->[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]>.<<<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fx0YbDqJ17YBI207bxiYWyLLRtou107MBcv7/dwQA)

Same IO as [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92519/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
₀ɾ*
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%80%C9%BE*&inputs=20&header=&footer=)

10-range-product-by-input

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
TR×
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS0KCDk9fUpyUXAwVWLDIyADCAgA)

##### Explanation

```python
TR×  # Implicit input
T    # Push 10
 R   # One-range
  ×  # Multiply
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 15 bytes

```ruby
:& &:*|~:*&10.+
```

Not much shorter than the equivalent Ruby:

```ruby
->n{(1..10).map{n*_1}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboW663UFNSstGrqrLTUDA30tCGiywoU3KKNYiGcBQsgNAA)