# Draw an alphabet party hat

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, alphabet

Your task is to print this exact text:

```
            z
            yz
           xyz
           wxyz
          vwxyz
          uvwxyz
         tuvwxyz
         stuvwxyz
        rstuvwxyz
        qrstuvwxyz
       pqrstuvwxyz
       opqrstuvwxyz
      nopqrstuvwxyz
      mnopqrstuvwxyz
     lmnopqrstuvwxyz
     klmnopqrstuvwxyz
    jklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

**Case does not matter.**

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I suspect some people are just tired of all the alphabet-pattern ascii-art KC challenges.

Comment: Can we do it in uppercase?

Comment: @Downgoat Yes..

Comment: Also, can we output an array of lines rather than join them by newlines?

Comment: @Downgoat You need to join it by newlines.

Comment: Seriously though, *another* alphabet challenge?

Comment: Also, can I print trailing newlines?

Comment: @EriktheGolfer Yes

Comment: I enjoy these alphabet challenges. This one could easily re-branded as a Christmas tree.

Comment: Halp its my birthday and I do not freakin' want to learn ABCs again

Comment: Can I print a leading newline?

Answer (score 6):

## Cheddar, <s>50</s> <s>45</s> <s>42</s> 37 bytes

```
25|>0=>i->print" "*(i/2|0)+(65+i)@"90
```

Straightforward, but utilizes cheddar's consise ranging syntax (both numerical and alphabetical)

[Try it online!](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=MjV8PjA9PmktPnByaW50IiAiKihpLzJ8MCkrKDY1K2kpQCI5MA&input=)

### Explanation

```
25 |> 0 =>    // Map range [0, 26) (i.e. [25, 0] reversed) over....
   i -> 
     print    // Prints in it's own line...
     " " * (i/2 |0) +     // Number of spaces is floor(n/2).
                          // `|0` for flooring is hack from JS
     (65 + i) @" 90       // Char code range is this
```

`65` is char code for `A` and `90` for `Z`

Comment: `Z` is `90`, not `A`.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
A.svy12N;ï-ú,
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=QS5zdnkxMk47w68tw7DDl8OsLA&input=) (slightly different from above as `ú` isn't on TIO yet)

**Explanation**

1. Push alphabet
2. Compute the suffixes of the alphabet
3. Prepend 12-index/2 spaces
4. Print

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 70 bytes

Ported from [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97460/53667)'s answer, -2 bytes for replacing `-i-1` with `~i`

```python
for i in range(26):print' '*(12-i/2)+"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[~i:]
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure using map can yield a shorter alphabet, except maybe lowercase having higher values

Comment: Actually I'm not sure anymore. I think it wouldn't work for this anyway :( soz

Answer (score 4):

## R, <strike>67 66</strike> 59 bytes

EDIT: Saved a couple of bytes thanks to @rturnbull

```
for(i in 25:0)cat(rep(" ",i/2),letters[i:25+1],"\n",sep="")
```

Exploiting the fact that any number passed to the `rep` function is automatically rounded down to the closest integer (e.g. `rep("*",1.99) => "*"`) which means that the actual sequence passed is `floor(13-1:26/2)`:

```
12 12 11 11 10 10  9  9  8  8  7  7  6  6  5  5  4  4  3  3  2  2  1  1  0  0
```

Comment: This comes out shorter than my matrix attempt. Replace `14...-1` with `13`?

Comment: @JDL Ah yes of course. A remnant of attempting another approach

Comment: If you loop through `25:0` instead of `1:26`, you can change `13-i/2` to `i/2`, and simplify `(27-i):26` to `i:25+1`, saving 6 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
A.s.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fUa9YL/n/fwA)

```
A.s.c
A     Push 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
 .s   Push suffixes starting from the shortest one
   .c Centralize focused on the left
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>85</s> <s>75</s> <s>69</s> 68 bytes

```
for(s=a='',x=36;--x>9;)s+=` `.repeat(x/2-5)+(a=x.toString(36)+a)+`
`
```

*-1 byte thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97456/draw-an-alphabet-party-hat/97462?noredirect=1#comment372785_97462)*.

Comment: Isn't this a snippet rather than a function or program?

Comment: ````for(s=a='',x=36;--x>9;)s+=` `.repeat(x/2-5)+(a=x.toString(36)+a)+'#'```` 1B shorter

Comment: @l4m2 Brilliant!

Comment: Nice idea using base 36! +1

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, 52 bytes

```python
n=26;s=''
while n:n-=1;s=chr(97+n)+s;print n/2*' '+s
```

Accumulates the string `s` to print and updates the number of leading spaces `n/2`. A `while` loop terminating at `0` is a rare numerical loop than beats an `exec` loop (53 bytes):

```python
n=26;s=''
exec"n-=1;s=chr(97+n)+s;print n/2*' '+s;"*n
```

Also a 53-byte alternative:

```python
s=''
exec"s=chr(122-len(s))+s;print s.center(26);"*26
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 15 bytes

```
j_m+*/d2\ >GdUG
```

A program that prints the result to STDOUT.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j_m%2B%2a%2Fd2%5C+%3EGdUG&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
j_m+*/d2\ >GdUG  Program
             UG  Yield [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 26]
  m              Map over the range with variable d:
          >Gd      Yield alphabet with first d-1 letters discarded
   +               Prepend
     /d2             d//2
    *   \            spaces
 _               Reverse
j                Join on newlines
                 Implicitly print
```

Comment: Try `;` instead of `\ `

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-2 bytes thanks to @miles (formed a niladic chain I suspected existed but did not form)

```
ØaJ’H⁶ẋżṫJ$ṚY
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5hhSuKAmUjigbbhuovFvOG5q0ok4bmaWQ&input=)**

#### How?

```
ØaJ’H⁶ẋżṫJ$ṚY - Main link
Øa            - alphabet yield -> ['a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'y', 'z']
  J           -    range(length)      -> [1, 2, 3, ..., 25, 26]
   ’          -    decrement          -> [0, 1, 2, ..., 24, 25]
    H         -    halve              -> [0,.5  1, ..., 12, 12.5]
     ⁶        -    literal [' ']
      ẋ       -    repeat list        -> [[], [], [' '], ..., 12x' ', 12x' ']
          $   - last two links as a monad
         J    -     range(length)     -> [1, 2, 3, ..., 25, 26]
        ṫ     -     tail (vectorises) -> [['a'-'z'], ['b'-'z'], ..., ['y','z'], ['z']]
       ż      - zip
              -> [[[],['a'-'z']], [[],['b'-'z']], ..., [12x' ',['y','z']], [12x' ',['z]]]
           Ṛ  - reverse whole array
            Y - join with line feeds (implicit print)
```

Comment: I found a way to form a niladic chain starting with the alphabet `ØaJ’H⁶ẋżṫJ$ṚY` that saves 2 bytes

Comment: Do you think the explanation is correct?

Comment: Yeah just think of it as a monadic chain with a single argument being the alphabet

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 244 bytes

```
((((((()()()()())){}{}){}){}()){})((((()()()){}){}()){}){(({}[()]<>)<({}<(<>({})<>)>){({}[()]<(({})[()])>)}({}({})<>[({})]<>(((()()()){}){}){}())((<>)<>{<({}[()])><>([{}]())<>}<>[{}]<>{}){({}[()]<((((()()()()){}){}){})>)}((()()()()()){})><>)}<>
```

[Try it online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KCgoKCgoKCkoKSgpKCkoKSkpe317fSl7fSl7fSgpKXt9KSgoKCgoKSgpKCkpe30pe30oKSl7fSl7KCh7fVsoKV08Pik8KHt9PCg8Pih7fSk8Pik-KXsoe31bKCldPCgoe30pWygpXSk-KX0oe30oe30pPD5bKHt9KV08PigoKCgpKCkoKSl7fSl7fSl7fSgpKSgoPD4pPD57PCh7fVsoKV0pPjw-KFt7fV0oKSk8Pn08Plt7fV08Pnt9KXsoe31bKCldPCgoKCgoKSgpKCkoKSl7fSl7fSl7fSk-KX0oKCgpKCkoKSgpKCkpe30pPjw-KX08Pg&input=&args=LUE)

---

This should be readable enough as is. If you need it, I have a full explanation:

```
push 122 (z): ((((((()()()()())){}{}){}){}()){})
push 26:      ((((()()()){}){}()){})
loop 26 times (i = 25..0): {
 (
  i--, push to b stack:({}[()]<>)
  <
   put 122 from a stack under i: ({}<(<>({})<>)>)
   i times push letter-1: {({}[()]<(({})[()])>)}
   replace top 0 with 26-i: ({}({})<>[({})]<>(((()()()){}){}){}())
   devide by two: ((<>)<>{<({}[()])><>([{}]())<>}<>[{}]<>{})
   add spaces: {({}[()]<((((()()()()){}){}){})>)}
   push 10 (\n): ((()()()()()){})
  >
  flip stack back: <>
 push i--: ) 
}
flip to results stack: <>
```

Comment: `This should be readable enough as is.` You are talking about *Brain-Flak*, right?

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>72</s> 68 bytes

```c
m(i){for(char*k=&k[i=26];i;printf("%*c%s\n",--i/2+1,0,k))*--k=64+i;}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ô2òΘé8└
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=933295e98238c0&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `C`, 4 bytes

```
kz¦R
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=C&code=kz%C2%A6R&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
kz    # Lowercase backwards alphabet
  ¦   # Prefixes
   R  # Reverse each
      # 'C' flag - Center top of stack, join on newlines, and print
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 71 Bytes

```
for(;++$i<27;)echo str_pad(substr(join(range(a,z)),-$i),26," ",2)."\n";
```

Comment: `(26-$i)/2` → `13-$i/2`

Comment: Will it throw an error if you removed the last colon? Also, would be nice if you provided a link to an online website with example, ex. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Answer (score 1):

## [Turtlèd](http://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Turtl-d), <s>70</s> 68 bytes

note the trailing space

```
#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#' -{ -{ +.r_}' l[ l-]d,(*@!' r)(!@*)_}'
```

#### Try it online!

### How it works:

```
#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#              Set string var to this value
                            ' -           write space on first grid cell, string pointer-=1
                               {                                    } While cell is space
                                 -                 decrement string pointer
                                  {     }    While cell is space
                                    +.       increment string pointer, write pointed char
                                      r      move right
                                       _     write non-space if pointed char is last char

                                         '[space]   write space on cell
                                           l        move left
                                            [ l-]   move left, pointer-- until cell's space
                                                 d, move down, write character var \
                                                                           (initially *)

                                                   (*     ) if cell is *
                                                     @!     set char var=!
                                                       ' r  write space over *, move right

                                                           (!    ) if cell is !
                                                             @*    set char var=*
                                                               '[space] write space over !

                                                                 _ (explanation below)
                                               write (*|!) if pointed char is last char

                                                                   '[space]    Write space
```

### Human-readable explanation(?):

It uses the string var to contain the alphabet. Each iteration, it reduces the index by one, until it wraps around, and halts, after getting to the last line. For the alternating indents, it uses the char var. Each iteration it checks the char var and flips it. if it was * it shifts right, so the first character aligns, otherwise not, so the last character aligns.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7 ,<del>128</del> 127  bytes

Saved 1 byte.Thanks to kevin.

```java
String c(int n,String s,char v,String d){String c="";for(int j=0;j++<(n-1)/2;c+=" ");return n>0?c(--n,s=v+s,--v,d+c+s+"\n"):d;}
```

## ungolfed

```java
  class A {

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.print(c(26, "", (char)122, ""));
}
static String c(int n, String s, char v, String d){

    String c = "";

    for (int j = 0; j++ < (n - 1)/2; c += " ");

    return n > 0 ? c(--n, s = v + s, --v, d + c + s + "\n" ) : d;
}
}
```

Without an passing 122 in a function

## 132 bytes

```java
String c(String s,int n,String d){String c="";int v=96,j=0;for(;j++<(n-1)/2;c+=" ");return n>0?c(s=(char)(v+n--)+s,n,d+c+s+"\n"):d;}
```

## ungolfed

```java
  class A{

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.print(c("",26,""));

}
static String c(String s, int n, String d) {
    String c = "";
    int v = 96,j=0;
    for (; j++ < (n - 1)/2; c += " ");
    return n > 0 ? c(s = ( char) (v + n--) + s, n, (d + c + s + "\n")) : d;
     }
  }
```

Comment: You can remove the `=` at `d+=c+s+"\n"`. Also, you might want to format your ungolfed code a bit with indentations. I noticed that with some of your other answers as well. :)

Comment: oops! i did this mistake again,Shame to me.    ......ok @KevinCruijssen i am on it.

Comment: Can't you replace the `s=v+s` in the recursion with `s+=v`?

Comment: No..because the letters pattern are in backward.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 44 bytes

This is a port of @xnor's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97466/55508).

```
$n=26;say$"x($n/2),$@=chr(97+$n).$@while$n--
```

Needs `-E` (or `-M5.010`) to run :

```
perl -E '$n=26;say$"x($n/2),$@=chr(97+$n).$@while$n--';
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 64 bytes

```
(0..26).each{|x|puts' '*(12-x/2)+('a'..'z').to_a[~x..-1].join()}
```

Comment: A few comments:

You don't need to put the brackets after `join`

Calling `each` instead of `map` is unnecessary, since we don't care about what we're returning

You can call `last` on a range

Comment: Instead of `(0..26).map`, try `27.times`; instead of `('a'..'z').to_a`, `[*?a..?z]`; and instead of `.join`, `*""`.

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, SBCL, <s>83</s> 82 bytes

```lisp
(dotimes(i 27)(format t"~26:@<~a~>
"(subseq"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"(- 26 i))))
```

#### Explanation

```lisp
(dotimes(i 27) ; loop from i=0 to i=26
(format t"~26:@<~a~>
"(subseq"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"(- 26 i))))
;print out part of alphabet starting from character number 26-i (counting from zero)
;using justification (~26:@<~a~>) to center with weight 26 characters
```

*-1 using sugestion by ASCII-only to use `<enter>` instead of `~%`*

Comment: [82](https://tio.run/##DcE7EkAwEADQ3ikyqTaFJjNSGGNcJQgWEWx8i1w9vNfMSGuM0DqP1hAgk0pA53arPfM8SJVXRdChTDjQUZPZuK6b1nT9gOM028Wt207@OK/7eTmkTGYMxS/GDw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 92 bytes

```
set a {}
time {set a [format %c [expr 123-[incr i]]]$a;puts [format %[expr 13+$i/2]s $a]} 26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/OLVEIVGhuparJDM3VaEawo1Oyy/KTSxRUE1WiE6tKChSMDQy1o3OzEsuUsiMjY1VSbQuKC0pRiiDKjLWVsnUN4otVlBJjK1VMDL7/x8A)

## tcl, 94

```
set a {}
set i 123
time {set a [format %c [incr i -1]]$a;puts [format %[expr 74-$i/2]s $a]} 26
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/YLNFPD87640)

In the middle of the process, I accidentaly got the italic version of the hat:

## tcl, 94

```
set a {}
set i 123
time {set a [format %c [incr i -1]]$a;puts [format %[expr $i/2-24]s $a]} 26
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/XODP23160)

---

## tcl, 101

```
set a {}
set i 123
while \$i>97 {set a [format %c [incr i -1]]$a;puts [format %[expr ($i-48)/2]s $a]}
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/SKUV47523)

In the middle of the process, I accidentaly got the italic version of the hat:

## tcl, 99

```
set a {}
set i 123
while \$i>97 {set a [format %c [incr i -1]]$a;puts [format %[expr $i/2-24]s $a]}
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/YMWTD54657)

Comment: [92?](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/OLVEIVGhuparJDM3VaEawo1Oyy/KTSxRUE1WiE6tKChSMDQy1o3OzEsuUsiMjY1VSbQuKC0pRiiDKjLWVsnUN4otVlBJjK1VMDL7/x8A)

Comment: @ASCII-only thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 16 bytes

```
;C¬£SpY/2 +CsYÃw ·
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@2/tfGjNocXBBZH6RgrazsWRh5vLFQ5t//8fAA)

#### Explanation:

```
;C¬£SpY/2 +CsYÃw ·
;C                  // Alphabet shortcut
  ¬                 // Split into an array of chars
   £          Ã     // Map each item X and index Y by:
    SpY/2           //  " " repeated floor(Y/2) times
          +CsY      //  + alphabet.slice(Y)
               w    // Reverse the array of lines
                 ·  // Join with newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

### REXX, 52 bytes

```
do i=1 to 26
  say centre(right(xrange(a,z),i),26)
  end
```

Output:

```
            Z             
            YZ            
           XYZ            
           WXYZ           
          VWXYZ           
          UVWXYZ          
         TUVWXYZ          
         STUVWXYZ         
        RSTUVWXYZ         
        QRSTUVWXYZ        
       PQRSTUVWXYZ        
       OPQRSTUVWXYZ       
      NOPQRSTUVWXYZ       
      MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ      
     LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ      
     KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ     
    JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ     
    IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ    
   HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ    
   GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ   
  FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ   
  EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ  
 DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ  
 CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 
BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 1):

## Vim, 25 Keystrokes

```
:h<_␍jjYZZPqqPxYPr Yq12@q
```

Where ␍ is the Enter key, also sometimes notated as `<cr>`.

### Explanation

```
:h<_␍jjYZZ                 " get a-z
          P                " initialize by pasting
           qq              " start record macro @q
             Px            " paste and remove the 1st char
               YPr␣        " yank and paste and replace 1st char with space
                   Y       " yank the whole line again
                    q      " end recording
                     12@q  " call macro 12 @q times
```

I am new to ViM though -- I started in November.  Wondering if there is a way to merge the initializing `P` with the one in the macro.

What is the "correct" way to test a golfed ViM sequence?  I tested with `\vi -u /dev/null`. However in a VM even `:h<_␍` doesn't work.  Also not very sure why my ViM will move to the first non space character haha.

P.S. Before I moved to use OS X, I golfed in Hexagony with great tools... Now on OS X I don't do wine and thus not running the great tools for explanations and debugging.  So started my journey with ViM!

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 112 bytes

```cs
()=>string.Join("\n",new int[26].Select((_,i)=>"".PadLeft(12-i/2)+"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".Substring(25-i)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBawIxEIXv@RUhFxN0s3ShlrLVy0ILxYKwhx7aUmJ21GnXpCZZrRV/@xpRixR6nJk373087RNtHbSNRzOj5cYHWOTkcpKFrWvQAa3x8gEMONR/FCM0y5zoWnlPx1uSplwMhgbWFE14yfpvsoSDA@fvPTxdfHDRgHdop0evsgTTTHQv9lzPlRM86yfYvb0R8U0QH1RATe8bo@@OsiEtg0JXKA90QNtD6vEgHy0azl4N6/2PwZgcq2oE08DPBExNdAXT2Rw/PuuFsV9L50OzWn9vfpgsm8mJLrtOIpBoc3KGWlms6JOKoYJsSRGrsjXIZ4cBYjnAfzm5EDnZkV27Bw)

```cs
()=>string.Join("\n", // OP doesnt want to output a sequence of string...
    new int[26].Select((_,i)=> // yield range from 0 to 25
        "".PadLeft(12-i/2)+ // add spaces to center
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".Substring(25-i)))  // remove letters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Dom Hastings*

```perl
say$"x(13+--$x/2),@a[$x..-1]for@a=a..z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFqULD0FhbV1elQt9IU8chMVqlQk9P1zA2Lb/IIdE2UU@v6v//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Comment: Came up with a slightly different variation for -2: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFqULD0FhbV1elQt9IU8chMVqlQk9P1zA2Lb/IIdE2UU@v6v//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 107 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(99)=SPACE(13),@ INT=27a:SET @t=STUFF(@t,@/2,@%2,CHAR(@+95))PRINT @t
SET @-=1IF @>1GOTO a
```

Modifies the string for each line by cramming in the correct letter at the correct position using the SQL fuction `STUFF()`. Formatted:

```sql
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(99)=SPACE(13), @ INT=27
a:
    SET @t=STUFF(@t,@/2,@%2,CHAR(@+95))
    PRINT @t
    SET @-=1
IF @>1 GOTO a
```

`@/2` uses integer division (no remainder) to determine the position to insert the letter. `@%2` is the `MODULO` function, and flips between 0 (insert the letter) and 1 (overwrite a space).

If you prefer capitial letters, use `CHAR(@+63)` instead (doesn't change our byte count).

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>62</s> <s>51</s> 46 bytes

<sup>-11 bytes thanks to mazzy reminding me of a function</sup>
<sup>-5 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
25..0|%{' '*($_-shr1)+-join('a'..'z')[$_..25]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/38hUT8@gRrVaXUFdS0MlXrc4o8hQU1s3Kz8zT0M9UV1PT71KXTNaJV5Pz8g0tvb/fwA)

Uses the <s>`-replace`</s> `-shift-right 1` trick to bypass banker's rounding. Additionally, uses a character range to generate the alphabet.

Comment: `-shr1` instead `-replace` :)

Comment: @mazzy D'oh. I even scrolled passed that tip while looking something else up. Thanks

Comment: What do you think about using the the [Powershell 5+](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/38hUT8@gRrVaXUFdS0MlXrc4o8hQU1s3Kz8zT0M9UV1PT71KXTNaJV5Pz8g0tvb/fwA "PowerShell – Try It Online") features by default?

Comment: @mazzy I think at this point, it's probably fine and we should instead specify an earlier version if you need a specific feature.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell (Lambdabot), 73 bytes

```
unlines[([1..div(26-length x)2]>>" ")++x|x<-reverse.init$tails['a'..'z']]
```

same length:

```
do x<-reverse.init$tails['a'..'z'];([1..div(26-length x)2]>>" ")++x++"\n"
```

I use `init.tails` or `tail.inits` with a possible reverse in front in pretty much every challenge; I wish they would add it to Prelude already.

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, <s>18</s> 12 bytes

```
26Fed*Gi>+)X
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=26Fed%2aGi%3E%2B%29X)

```
26F       )  -  for i in range(26):
   ed*       -    (i//2)*" "
         +   -   concatenate ↑ and ↓
      Gi>    -    alphabet[i:]
           X - splat(^) (print list reversed with newlines)
```

#### Or 10 bytes noncompetitive

```
26DXF2GR>c
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=26DXF2GR%3Ec)

Comment: Is it `splat` or `split`?

Comment: @EriktheGolfer it is splat. It pops a list and pushes the contents of that list in reverse to the stack

Comment: Okay, putting the spellcheck edit in.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, <s>66</s> 64 bytes

```
i=91;exec'i-=1;print`map(chr,range(i,91))`[2::5].center(26);'*26
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-your-language-one-vote-at-a-time/86385#86385), 57 bytes

```
[25,0,-1|Y=Z[1,a/2|Y=Y+@ |]X=Z[a,25|X=X+$CHR$(65+|c)]?Y+X
```

This one works surprisingly well with QBIC' FOR loops.
Explanation (of previous version - same principle applies):

```
[26,1,-1|          Loops from 26 to 1, decrementing 'a'
                   'a' is used to determine the number of spaces per line and the last letter we want to print
Y=Z                Z is always an empty string in this program, 
                   Y will hold the spaces we need to center this line
[1,a/2|Y=Y+@ |]    Add a space to Y equal to half the value of 'a', giving us a center alignment
X=Z                X holds the characters we need on this line, reset it
[a,26|             FOR c = a to 26 --> loop over the last part of the alphabet
X=X+$CHR$(64+|c)]  Convert c+64 to ASCII and append
?Y+X               Print the spaces and the letters

<outer FOR loop is closed by QBIC>
```

Output:

```
            Z
            YZ
           XYZ
           WXYZ
          VWXYZ
          UVWXYZ
         TUVWXYZ
         STUVWXYZ
        RSTUVWXYZ
        QRSTUVWXYZ
       PQRSTUVWXYZ
       OPQRSTUVWXYZ
      NOPQRSTUVWXYZ
      MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
     LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
     KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
   HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
   GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
  FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
  EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
 DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
 CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: Doesn't match the OP.

Comment: @carusocomputing it does now.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 53 bytes

```
('z'..'a').each{println((it..'z').join().center(26))}
```

## Output:

```
            z             
            yz            
           xyz            
           wxyz           
          vwxyz           
          uvwxyz          
         tuvwxyz          
         stuvwxyz         
        rstuvwxyz         
        qrstuvwxyz        
       pqrstuvwxyz        
       opqrstuvwxyz       
      nopqrstuvwxyz       
      mnopqrstuvwxyz      
     lmnopqrstuvwxyz      
     klmnopqrstuvwxyz     
    jklmnopqrstuvwxyz     
    ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz    
   hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz    
   ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz   
  fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz   
  efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz  
 defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz  
 cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 137 bytes

```
(for((n(range 122 96 -1)))(for((i(floor(/(- n 97)2))))(display #\space))
(for((i(range n 123)))(display(integer->char i)))(displayln ""))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f)
  (for ((n (range 122 96 -1)))
       (for ((i (floor(/(- n 97)2))))
         (display #\space))
       (for ((i (range n 123)))
         (display (integer->char i)))
    (displayln "")))
```

Testing:

```
(f)
```

Output:

```
            z
            yz
           xyz
           wxyz
          vwxyz
          uvwxyz
         tuvwxyz
         stuvwxyz
        rstuvwxyz
        qrstuvwxyz
       pqrstuvwxyz
       opqrstuvwxyz
      nopqrstuvwxyz
      mnopqrstuvwxyz
     lmnopqrstuvwxyz
     klmnopqrstuvwxyz
    jklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 175 Bytes:

Golfed:

```
string H(){string o="",a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";int p=12,i=0;for(i=0;i<=26;i++){o+=a.Substring(26-i,i).PadLeft(p+i)+"\n";if(i==0||i==1)continue;p-=i%2==0?1:0;}return o;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public string H()
{
  string o = "", a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  int p = 12, i=0;
  for (i = 0; i <= 26; i++)
  {
    o += a.Substring(26 - i, i).PadLeft(p+i)+ "\n";
    if (i == 0 || i == 1) continue;
    p -= i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  }
  return o;
}
```

Test:

```
Console.Write(new DrawAnAlphabetHat().H());
```

Output:

```
            z
            yz
           xyz
           wxyz
          vwxyz
          uvwxyz
         tuvwxyz
         stuvwxyz
        rstuvwxyz
        qrstuvwxyz
       pqrstuvwxyz
       opqrstuvwxyz
      nopqrstuvwxyz
      mnopqrstuvwxyz
     lmnopqrstuvwxyz
     klmnopqrstuvwxyz
    jklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 133 Bytes

```
for(i=26,s="";i>0;i--){for(k=26-i+Math.floor((i+1)/2),l=34+Math.floor((i+1)/2);k>0;k--,l--)k>27-i?s+=" ":s+=l.toString(36);s+="<br>"}
```

[Try it here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRBQEQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
z{Xf}¹№╚
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=eiU3QlhmJTdEJUI5JXUyMTE2JXUyNTVB)

Explanation:

```
z         push the lowercase alphabet
 {  }     for each, pushing current character
  X         remove the character from the stack as it's not needed
   f        push the remaining string, including the current character, what the loop has to traverse
     ¹    wrap all that in an array
      №   reverse vertically
       ╚  center horizontally - this centers it exactly as required :D
```

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, <sub><s>68</s></sub> 66 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate function that takes no input and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
For i=1To 26:?:?Spc(13-i/2);:For j=27-i To 26:?Chr(j+96);:Next j,i
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 125 bytes

```cs
()=>{var s="";for(var c='z';c>'`';c--){for(var i='a';i<'{';i++)s+=i<c?' ':i;s+="\n";}Console.WriteLine(s.Replace("  "," "));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYkxDgIhEEWvMqEBsq4HENEYW220sLEQRzSTrLBh0Khkz75iYfN@3vvILTKOD6Zwg/2bs7@b/nHuCAE7xwx9irfk7gU4u1zrM9IFto6C0lBghZligBfYUWm7KE@XgK0Q5hqT@gla@ZEGF/JU2ba6/A@y0klDc1kqm0ZzY2mOSwlyRqaKOAZhhnUMHDs/PSTKfkPBK57ufN859EoAiIkAobUZRvNSdYbxCw)

Highlights: seen how char is a numeric datatype, let's use it for the loop. The value ranges from 'a' to 'z', which is awesome! We can just add a char to a string, so that's another back-curling - but now convenient - feature.

The outer counter counts from z to a, the inner counter from a to z. The inner loop checks if the inner counter is more than the outer, if so print a space, else print the counter character. After every outer iteration we print a newline, after the function completes we print it to the console after replacing a double space with a single one (very, very wasteful line, but included in character count).

I couldn't think of any more abuse in a language specification than this.

EDIT: added lambda function specification and call in accordance to alois' remark.

Comment: Hello fellow C# golfer. We are not allowed to post a snippet, but we can use a function and lamda are allowed. [source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85053/15214).

Comment: Got it, alois. Sorry for being too short through. Are we allowed to not print but output the text, and leave the printing and line breaking to an outside-the-function loop-and-print? If so, i'll have a go at shaving off those characters again! Thanks dude,

Comment: most of the time we can, but here OP want to output a string with "\n"...

Answer (score 0):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 101 bytes

```fs
[0..25]|>Seq.map(fun i->"".PadLeft(12-i/2)+"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".[25-i..])|>String.concat "\n"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxNDoIwEEDhq0wmMYGYjtqEpZzAhYlLZFFLB6vQQin@hbtX3vJbPJ6E9sGkzkRgOCZYq/ZEsqiX8mJG6tWQ8ezAihKRzqo5GY7ZQQq7k/kW1U03htu7fTy73vlhDFOcX@/P94dUyUJYojpfTzFY15L2TqsIeHWYGJYShpUjO8DNhOkP)

A naive port of my [C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148313/15214)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 54 bytes

```ruby
puts (0..25).map{|c|[*(90-c).chr..'Z'].join.center 26}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFhBw0BPz8hUUy83saC6JrkmWkvD0kA3WVMvOaNIT089Sj1WLys/M08vOTWvJLVIwcis9v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
Ｆ²⁷«Ｐ⮌…⮌βι¿﹪ι²↓↙
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw8hcU6GaS0HBtzSnJDOgKDOvRCMotSy1qDhVwzc/JwXOSdLUydTU1LQGKs1MUwDKpZTm5Gtk6hhpair45pelali55JfnaVojcXxS00qAGmr///@vW5YDAA)

Link is to the verbose version of the code. I'm sure there must be a shorter way to do this in Charcoal.

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8otSy1qDhVwzexQMPITEdBW0NLQ0lBSUfBIzGnLDVFI1NTU0chOCczOVUjSUcByNO0/v//v25ZDgA), I think

Comment: @ASCII-only 11 bytes: [`⮌Ｅβ⁺× ⊘κ✂βκ`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCMotSy1qDhVwzexQCNJRyEgp7RYIyQzN7VYQ0lBSUfBIzGnLDVFI1tTU0chOCczORWkCMjT1LT@//@/blkOAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 39 bytes

```
echo(' '<@#"0~2#i._13),&><@|.\u:90-i.26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19DXUHdxkFZyaDOSDlTL97QWFNHzc7GoUYvptTK0kA3U8/I7P9/AA)

I see capital letters in some submissions so I assume it's OK to use them. If not, then add a byte to convert to lowercase.

#### Explanation

See my (almost identical) answer to [this (duplicate) question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152563/42833).

The only difference is in generating the alphabet, where I generate `ZYX...CBA` and then reverse each prefix of that string to give the desired parts. I feel like there is a way to avoid that but I'm tired right now and this is the best way of fixing it that I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 82 bytes

A jolly solution that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
For i=1To 26
For j=1To 13-i/2
?" ";
Next
For j=27-i To 26
?Chr$(j+96);
Next
?
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3y2/SCHT1jAkX8HIjAvEyQJzDI11M/WNuOyVFJSsufxSK0qgckbmupkKEMX2zhlFKhpZ2pZmmlAl9mDq/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 75 bytes

Anonymous function that takes no input and outputs to the console.

Slightly different approach than other BASIC answers as uBASIC's integer division functions differently - (`25/2` equals `12` rather than `13`)

```
0ForI=2To27:?Tab(13-I/2);:ForJ=28-ITo26:?Left$(Chr$(J+96),1);:NextJ:?:NextI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwC2/yNPWKCTfyNzKPiQxScPQWNdT30jT2goo4WVrZKHrCZQzs7L3SU0rUdFwzihS0fDStjTT1DEEqvFLrSjxsrIH057//wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 20 bytes

```apl
(⌈13-.5×⍳26)⌽⌽↑,\⌽⎕a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CYb////XeNTTYWisq2d6ePqj3s1GZpqPevaCUNtEnRgQ3Tc1EQA)

uses `⎕io←1`

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>68 58</s> 57 bytes

edit #1: a different approach with left padding and string concatenation + uppercase
edit #2: shorter padding expression

```php
while($i++<26)printf("
%".($i+26>>1).s,$s=chr(91-$i).$s);
```

Add two bytes if a leading newline is disallowed:

```php
while($i++<26)printf("%".($i+26>>1)."s
",$s=chr(91-$i).$s);
```

Run with `-nr` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1759e39f150259f020a7715c2e8be9ea75cd68a).

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 22 bytes

```
asFa`z9sL-F:M|L2,R` |H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/P7HYLTGhyrLYR9fNyrfGx0gnKEGhxuP/fwA)

#### How it works

```
asFa`z9sL-F:M|L2,R` |H

asF                 |   Repeat 26 times...
   a                      Push 10 (\n)
    `z                    Push z
      9sL-F  |            Repeat (25 - loop counter(L)) times...
           :M               Clone the top and decrement
              L2,R        Repeat (L / 2) times...
                  `         Push 32 (space)
                     H  Output the entire content (top to bottom) and halt
```

Basically, this constructs the entire output backwards.

There are two division operators in `Gol><>`, namely `,` (floating division) and `S,` (integer division). Luckily `R` (repeat X times) floors its argument, so I could save a byte.

Answer (score 0):

**Java 10: 136 bytes**

**GOLFED**

```
for(int i=25;i>=0;i--){for(int j=0;j<i/2;j++){System.out.print(" 
");}System.out.println("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".substring(i,26));}}
```

**UNGOLFED**

```
class a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 25; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i/2; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".substring(i,26));
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULTS**

```
            z
            yz
           xyz
           wxyz
          vwxyz
          uvwxyz
         tuvwxyz
         stuvwxyz
        rstuvwxyz
        qrstuvwxyz
       pqrstuvwxyz
       opqrstuvwxyz
      nopqrstuvwxyz
      mnopqrstuvwxyz
     lmnopqrstuvwxyz
     klmnopqrstuvwxyz
    jklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! One thing: your code doesn't seem to run, on [TIO](https://tio.run/##XcxLDoIwFIXhrZCO2iDVNNFJxU24giIP7wVa6ANFwtprJ06cfv/JQbWoAus@xtZYCtpnUIqzhFt5klAUbPsxJsArHIXEPGfbfXW@GbkJnk82dUoywuT@z4OmRFWPumm7J2A/jNpMs3U@LK/3@iHchcr5NOwoHMSFpYc9xi8) at least. Also, it's a good idea to add a TIO link to your answer.

Comment: Your current *GOLFED* submission seems to be a snippet, which is [not allowed here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/64121). What you can do to make this a valid submission is to convert this into a function, which can be [done in 139 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY/NDoIwEITvPsWGUxsFDYleKr6BXDgaD6WAboWCtOBfeHZcf@LBZPcws7PJN1r20tfZaVSltBa2Es1jAoDG5W0hVQ7xSwL0NWagGBekBloa66RDBTEYiGBk3N88irpl9AoYhUuBm2gh0Pf5z9Zk6DXOQ6GnU57crMuroO5c0LR0Zh54XPy7pWGeTFWWF4cj6lNZmbo5t9Z1/eV6u3uB7VLrKHhgOAtXnIthGF@QTZeWRPeFfONXVI4l7/BuD5J/mpngV2sYnw).

Comment: Not an expert with Java, but can't you use the `repeat` function for [109 bytes](https://tio.run/##Pc7NDoIwDAfwu0/RcNqiTEOiF4JvoBePxkMZQ4swcBsoEp4d50dM2sM/bdNfgR2GRXadZInWwg5JDzMA0k6ZHKWC/TsCdDVlIBmPfRp9@7IOHUnYg4YEJsbD7ZDXhvlToCRax7RNVjGFIT/01qlK1K0TjfHjUrMAAmFUo9AxWkZ8HmAqM5WfL1Rcy0rXzc1Y13b3R/8MhG1T6/zhmdEi2nAej9Ob0bRp6f//GB9g5fns8Nk9ngD5167FHz5OLw "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")?

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
ｚ±［±］ｒ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjVBJUIxJXVGRjNCJUIxJXVGRjNEJXVGRjUy,v=8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;CÔåi û
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=O0PU5Wkg%2bw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 99 bytes

```elixir
import Enum
reduce 25..0,'            ',&(IO.puts(&2++slice(?a..?z,&1,26))&&rem(&1,2)>0&& &2||tl&2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v8/M7cgv6hEwTWvNJerKDWlNDlVwchUT89AR10BCajrqGl4@usVlJYUa6gZaWsX52Qmp2rYJ@rp2VfpqBnqGJlpaqqpFaXmaoA4mnYGamoKakY1NSU5akaa//8DAA)

Trying to find another way to generate the space string but can't make anything shorter...