# Print the alphabet Christmas tree

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, alphabet

I know it's 1.5 weeks after Christmas but trying to print an isosceles triangle in a monospaced font makes it look weird.

## Challenge

Print the alphabet from A to Z so that it forms a filled triangle in the output.
For each line in the output, starting from "A", add the next letter.

No inputs, only outputs. Pad the leading edge of the triangle with spaces.

Best answer is the code with the least bytes.

## Output

```
            A
            AB
           ABC
           ABCD
          ABCDE
          ABCDEF
         ABCDEFG
         ABCDEFGH
        ABCDEFGHI
        ABCDEFGHIJ
       ABCDEFGHIJK
       ABCDEFGHIJKL
      ABCDEFGHIJKLM
      ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
     ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
     ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU
  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

## Sample Java Code (430 bytes)

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String spaces = "";
    String alpha = "";
    char A = 'A';

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        for (int j = 13 - (i/2); j > 0; j--) {
           spaces += " ";
        }

        alpha += (char)(A + i);

        System.out.println(spaces + alpha);
        spaces = "";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and nice first challenge! Another tag that is appropriate is kolmogorov-complexity. And most likely someone will ask if leading and trailing newlines and spaces are allowed so specifying if they are might be a good idea.

Comment: Just a note... using `String` instead of `StringBuilder` in Java may cause bad performance. It's better use `StringBuilder` when you need to build a string. (don't argue with me that O(N) is O(1) when N is small, good coding practice is good anyway).

Comment: @user202729 But but O(N) is O(1) when N is small.

Comment: No one tell Leaky that alphabet challenges are back

Comment: Is lower case alphabet okay as well?

Comment: I guess that this is a lot easier than the other one at least in PHP: I can increment letters, but not decrement.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```ruby
t=''
26.times{|x|puts' '*(12-x/2)+(t<<65+x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8RWXZ3LyEyvJDM3tbi6pqKmoLSkWF1BXUvD0Ei3Qt9IU1ujxMbGzFS7QrP2/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
Auη.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fsfTcdr3k//8B)

**Exlpanation**

```
A        # push the alphabet
 u       # convert to upper case
  η      # get list of prefixes
   .c    # centralize, focused to the left
```

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
'⁸∫Zm}¹╚
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTI3JXUyMDc4JXUyMjJCWm0lN0QlQjkldTI1NUE_,v=0.12)

Explanation:

```
'⁸        push 26
  ∫  }    that many times, pushing the counter
   Zm       mold the alphabet to the counters length
      ¹   wrap the stack in an array
       ╚  center horizontally
```

Comment: You know your languages is built for kolmo challenges when you have a 'center horizontally' command.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/what-is-dotnet), 114 + 18 = 132 bytes

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##ZU9NT8JAEL3vr5j0NBvqCphwqZAgiAoFK1Xx81CXwWxSd2N3KyGG3163NDEmvtv7mJc30h5JU1BVWqXfId1ZRx8R@8tErPRnxJjMM2shYd8MPKzLnJLwZdQa5pnSyA9yY9aYlFqeWlf4ogFsPIE@VMj7g0YTU@OPghcdhJq2oLR77vZeRUo5SYeoQvLRYHg2Gp9PLi6vprN4vrhObpbp7d396uHxKRBp@dZUYTukVoeLJFvHtHHYOWlhLRx3OedV9LtoZLQ1OYlVoRz5pwjrWcj5/8iSfFed8N7B3LM9q34A)

```
()=>string.Join("\n",new int[26].Select((i,e)=>"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".Substring(0,e+1).PadLeft(13+(e+1)/2)))
```

Comment: Can you use a function with a dummy argument (`_=>`) to save a byte?

Comment: thats what I usually do but OP said "No inputs" so I thought lets honor that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sub><s>38</s></sub> 36 bytes

```
echo(' '<@#"0~2#i._13),&><\u:65+i.26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19DXUHdxkFZyaDOSDlTL97QWFNHzc4mptTKzFQ7U8/I7P9/AA)

This is honestly disgusting.

## 39 bytes

```
echo(2#i._13)(>@],~' '#~[)"0<\u:65+i.26
```

## Explanation

These will be snippets of the code built up from a REPL session. Three spaces means an input, and no spaces means the output from it.

#### The alphabet

First we generate the alphabet by making the range [65,90] and converting this to unicode using `u:`.

```
   65 + i.10 NB. truncated
65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74
   u: 65 + i.26
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Then we generate the `A`, `AB`, etc. sections by taking all of the prefixes of the alphabet and boxing them using `<\`

```
   <\ u: 65 + i.5 NB. truncated again
┌─┬──┬───┬────┬─────┐
│A│AB│ABC│ABCD│ABCDE│
└─┴──┴───┴────┴─────┘
```

#### The padding

We need to pad the alphabet with 12, 12, 11, 11, etc. spaces. So first we construct this range using `i.` with a negative argument (which makes it go from that value minus 1 to 0, descending).

```
   i. _13
12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

We then copy each value twice

```
   2 # i. _13
12 12 11 11 10 10 9 9 8 8 7 7 6 6 5 5 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 1 0 0
```

And then copy the space character as many times as specified, boxing it because J would pad the matrix with spaces to fill otherwise.

```
   '*' #"0~ 2 # i. _5 NB. truncated, and using '*' so you can see the output
****
****
*** 
*** 
**  
**  
*   
*   
    NB. This line is empty
    NB. This line is empty, too
```

#### Getting the output

Then we just join the two together using `,` (unboxing first using `&>`) and write to STDOUT using `echo`. There's nothing to show here since it's just the output.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel (VBA), <s>129</s> 82 bytes

Using Immediate Window.  <s>and cell `[A1]` as output.</s>

```vb
For x=25to 0Step -1:For y=x to 25:b=b &Chr(65+y-x):Next:?Space(x/2.01)&b:b="":Next
```

Comment: You can make some small changes to get to `For x=-25To 0:For y=Abs(x)To 25:b=b+Chr(65+y+x):Next:?Spc(x/-2.1)b:b="":Next` or some bigger changes and get to `For x=-25To 0:?Spc(x/-2.01);:For y=Abs(x)To 25:?Chr(65+y+x);:Next:?:Next` (72 Bytes)

Comment: Noted and Thank you. :) Will apply it for future challenge :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 32 bytes

```perl
say$"x(13-++$k/2),A..$_ for A..Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFqULD0FhXW1slW99IU8dRT08lXiEtv0gByIr6//9ffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0MDAA)

Answer (score 0):

## C,  <s>84</s>  81 bytes

*Thanks to @ceilingcat for saving three bytes!*

```c
f(i,j){for(i=1;i++<27;puts(""))for(j=51;j<63-~i/2;)putchar(j++<64-i/2?32:j+i/2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1MnS7M6Lb9II9PW0DpTW9vGyNy6oLSkWENJSVMTJJ5la2ponWVjZqxbl6lvZK0JlEzOSASKA9WamegCxeyNjayytIEMTeva/5l5JQq5iZl5Gppc1VwKQJCmoWnNVfsfAA)

**Unrolled:**

```c
f(i, j) // Using the argument list only to declare the variables.
{
    for (i=1; i++<27; puts(""))
        for (j=51; j<63-~i/2;)
            putchar(j++<64-i/2 ? 32 : j+i/2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ØAJ’HU⁶ẋż¹ƤY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//w5hBSuKAmUhV4oG24bqLxbzCucakWf//)

Uses code very similar to the linked question (further evidence that it is most likely a dupe).

-3 bytes thanks to FlipTack and Jonathan Allan (though indirectly)

### Old version, 15 bytes

```
12Rx2U⁶ẋżØA¹Ƥ¤Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//MTJSeDJV4oG24bqLxbzDmEHCucakwqRZ//8)

Comment: You may want to look at [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97467/60919), though I suspect this question will soon be closed as a duplicate of that one anyway.

Comment: @FlipTack I've already VTC'ed, and thanks for the byte save!

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
øＺ［∔｝ｒ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JUY4JXVGRjNBJXVGRjNCJXUyMjE0JXVGRjVEJXVGRjUy,v=8)