# Illustrate the Least Common Multiple

Tags: code-golf, math, ascii-art, number, integer

Given two positive integers, \$A\$ and \$B\$, illustrate their [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) by outputting two lines of dashes (`-`) with length [\$\text{lcm}\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)\$(A, B)\$ after replacing every \$A\$th dash in the first line and every \$B\$th dash in the second line with vertical bars (`|`).

In this way, the end of each line will be the only place two `|`'s line up.

> For example, if \$A = 6\$ and \$B = 4\$, \$\text{lcm}(6, 4) = 12\$, so:
>
> ```
> two lines of 12 dashes:
> ------------
> ------------
>
> replace every 6th dash in the first line with a vertical bar:
> -----|-----|
> ------------
>
> replace every 4th dash in the second line with a vertical bar:
> -----|-----|
> ---|---|---|
> ```
>
> Thus the final output would be
>
> ```
> -----|-----|
> ---|---|---|
> ```

The order of the input numbers should correspond to the order of the lines.

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

## Testcases

```
A B
line for A
line for B

1 1
|
|

1 2
||
-|

2 1
-|
||

2 2
-|
-|

6 4
-----|-----|
---|---|---|

4 6
---|---|---|
-----|-----|

2 3
-|-|-|
--|--|

3 2
--|--|
-|-|-|

3 6
--|--|
-----|

2 5
-|-|-|-|-|
----|----|

4 3
---|---|---|
--|--|--|--|

10 10
---------|
---------|

10 5
---------|
----|----|

10 6
---------|---------|---------|
-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|

24 8
-----------------------|
-------|-------|-------|

7 8
------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|

6 8
-----|-----|-----|-----|
-------|-------|-------|

13 11
------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

Comment: @LeakyNun Extending an answer from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/94999 seems easier than from that one. Either way, people will have fun doing this one which is a decent reason imo.

Comment: Can I output an array with two strings, one for each line?

Comment: @BlackCap No. Print the strings to stdout or a file or return the whole multiline string.

Comment: Bonus for handling arbitrary number of inputs?

Comment: Is a leading new-line allowed if the rest of the output is correct?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen that sounds ok.

Comment: @HelkaHomba Ok thanks; saved 1 more byte. :) (As if there is any other reason to ask such questions on codegolf challenges. ;p)

Answer (score 11):

## Python 3, 80 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to Halvard Hummel and 1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan.

```
import math
def f(*l):
 for k in 0,1:print(l[~k]//math.gcd(*l)*(~-l[k]*"-"+"|"))
```

[Test it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxCoAgFADQvVN8nNQyi6Khq4hDZJZoKuIShFc3evOLT76Cn2o1dwwpw73lq1GHBo2pI2sDOiSwYDwM3bjGZHzGThQrOf9rf@7qjxQX5oSVFDHUohcRUjWeu4XUDw)

```
lambda*l:"\n".join(l[0]*l[1]//math.gcd(*l)//k*(~-k*"-"+"|")for k in l)
import math
```

[Test it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxDsIgEADQ3a8gN92hLRpNBxO/pO2ANljkOAhhMTH9dRrf/PK3rkmuzT2mxjY@F6v5DpNA/0lekMfzrHm8zMZEW9f@/VpQMxkTNG5d0NDBEX5ALhUVlBfFdPAxp1LV/7dcvFR0OJxuRG0H) (82 bytes - initial answer)

This is the best I could do in Python 2 (81 bytes). It seems like I cannot comment on that answer, I'll just post this here instead:

```
from fractions import*
l=a,b=input()
for k in l:print a*b/gcd(*l)/k*(~-k*"-"+"|")
```

[Test it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1chrSgxuSQzP69YITO3IL@oRIsrxzZRJ8k2M6@gtERDkystv0ghWyEzTyHHqqAoM69EIVErST89OUVDK0dTP1tLo043W0tJV0lbqUZJ8///aDMdk1gA)

*First attempt here, probably sub-optimal!*

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @Laikoni Thank you! This seems like a fun community :-)

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSvHSikmT0kvKz8zTyMnui47Vl8/N7EkQy89OUVDK0dTS6NONyc6O1ZLSVdJW6lGSTMtv0ghWyEzL9pAxzBWkysztyC/qEQBpOV/QVFmXolGmoaZjomm5n8A)

Comment: @HalvardHummel Thanks, will post as an alternative!

Comment: While trying a diferent approach entirely I realised your version could be done [in 80](https://tio.run/##FcoxCoAgFADQvVN8nNQyi6Khq4hDZJZoKuIShFc3evOLT76Cn2o1dwwpw73lq1GHBo2pI2sDOiSwYDwM3bjGZHzGThQrOf9rf@7qjxQX5oSVFDHUohcRUjWeu4XUDw).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 57 bytes

```hs
x%y=unlines[["-|"!!(0^mod a b)|a<-[1..lcm x y]]|b<-[x,y]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0K10rY0LyczL7U4OlpJt0ZJUVHDIC43P0UhUSFJsybRRjfaUE8vJzlXoUKhMja2JgkoUKEDZP3PTczMU7BVKCgtCS4pUlBRMFE1/Q8A)

Comment: I've never seen that `0^0=1` trick before - clever

Comment: @BlackCap I can't claim it myself because I have seen it a few times before, though I don't remember where I saw the trick first.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
Ṭ€ị⁾|-ṁ€æl/Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzjWPmtY83N39qHFfje7DnY1A3uFlOfqR////jzbTUTCJBQA)

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
'-|'!i&Zm:G\go)
```

Input is a column vector with the two numbers. [**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X123Rl0xUy0q18o9Jj1f8///aDNrBYtYAA)

As a bonus, the input can contain *more than two numbers*. [**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X123Rl0xUy0q18o9Jj1f8///aGNrBRNrBQtrBbNYAA)

#### Explanation

```
'-|'   % Push this string
!      % Transpose. This is needed because of input [1; 1]
i      % Input column vector of 2 (or N) numbers
&Zm    % LCM of the 2 (or N) numbers, say L
:      % Range
G      % Push input again
\      % Modulus, element-wise with broadcast. Gives a 2×L (or N×L) matrix
g      % Convert to logical: gives false for zeros, true for nonzeros
o      % Convert to double: gives 0 for false, 1 for true
)      % Index into string (modular, 1-based). Implicitly display
```

Comment: I think you left in a stray `He`?

Comment: @Sanchises Thanks! Yes, it was in the previous version, but it's not necessary

Comment: Also, this seems to work just fine without the transpose? You've been overthinking things... ;)

Comment: @Sanchises Without the transpose it doesn't work for input `[1; 1]`, due to how MATL(AB) handles array shape with indexing. (Alternatively, the transpose could be replaced by `He` at the end, which is why it was initially there)

Comment: Ah yes I figured that it was there because of row behaviour but I didn't think of this edge case.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>109</s> 105 bytes

```r
function(a,b){q=1:a*b
l=min(q[!q%%a])
x=rep("-",l*2)
x[c(seq(0,l,a),l+seq(0,l,b))]="|"
write(x,"",l,,"")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfbqP7P600L7kkMz9PI1EnSbO60NbQKlEriSvHNjczT6MwWrFQVTUxVpOrwrYotUBDSVdJJ0fLCMiNTtYoTi3UMNDJ0UnU1MnRhnGSNDVjbZVqlLjKizJLUjUqdJSAOnSApGbt/3QNMx0Tzf8A)

Anonymous function. Computes `l=lcm(a,b)`, then generates a range from `0` to `l` by `a`, then from `l` to `2*l` by `b`, setting the indices to `|` and printing as a matrix with `l` columns.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 66 bytes

```python
l=a,b=input()
while a%b:a+=l[0]
for x in l:print a/x*('-'*~-x+'|')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8c2USfJNjOvoLREQ5OrPCMzJ1UhUTXJKlHbNifaIJYrLb9IoUIhM08hx6qgKDOvRCFRv0JLQ11XXatOt0JbvUZd8/9/Cx0zAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

```
†?'-'|TUṪ`%N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDAnt1XfWakNCHO1clqPr9//8/2kTHLBYA)

Yeah, there is a lcm builtin in Husk. No, I don't need it.

Bonus: works with any number of input values

#### Explanation

```
†?'-'|TUṪ`%N    input:[2,3]
        Ṫ`%N    table of all remainders of positive naturals divided by
                input numbers:
                             [[1,1],[0,2],[1,0],[0,1],[1,2],[0,0],[1,1],[0,2],...
       U        get all elements before the first repeated one:
                             [[1,1],[0,2],[1,0],[0,1],[1,2],[0,0]]
      T         transpose:   
                             [[1,0,1,0,1,0],[1,2,0,1,2,0]]
†?'-'|          replace all truthy elements with '-' and all falsy elements
                with '|': 
                             ["-|-|-|","--|--|"]
                implicit: since this is a full program, join the resulting array
                of strings with newlines, and print to stdout
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 63 bytes

```
(s=LCM@##;Print[""<>If[i~Mod~#<1,"|","-"]~Table~{i,s}]&/@{##})&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfo9jWx9nXQVnZOqAoM68kWknJxs4zLTqzzjc/pU7ZxlBHqUZJR0lXKbYuJDEpJ7WuOlOnuDZWTd@hWlm5VlPtf1q0mY5F7H8A)

and another version which user202729 really, really, really wants to see posted

## Mathematica, 59 bytes

```
(s=LCM@##;Print[""<>If[#∣i,"|","-"]~Table~{i,s}]&/@{##})&
```

this one uses special character `\[Divides]`  `∣`

Comment: If this is Mathematica you can probably use `\[Divides]` instead of `Mod` operator to represent divisibility, which saves 4 bytes. Also Mathics TIO should not print the `{Null, Null}`.

Comment: @user202729 I fixed the Mathics print.

Comment: I think that your first comment was clear enough. Please stop pressing me in order to make the changes that you want, the exact time you want. Give the users some hours to respond. Some of us have a life out of this place

Answer (score 4):

## C, 72 bytes

```c
i;f(x,y){for(i=1;i%y|i%x;)putchar(i++%x?45:124);puts("|");y>0&&f(y,-x);}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>46</s> 38 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to several suggestions by Luis Mendo*

```matlab
@(a,b)'-|'.'(~mod(1:lcm(a,b),[a;b])+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjUSdJU123Rl1PXaMuNz9Fw9AqJzkXLKoTnWidFKupbaj5P03DUAdIAQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
ʒ<'-×'|«¹.¿∍,
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/8wNWFiMWX//8qSPCctw5cnfMKrwrkuwr/iiI0s//9bMywgMl0)

Comment: Filter was a good idea, I got 17 doing it entirely different `.¿Lε²¹‚%_„-|è}øJ»`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 69 bytes

```
f=(a,b,S,A=1)=>(A%a?'-':'|')+(A%a|A%b?f(a,b,S,A+1):S?'':`
`+f(b,a,1))
```

Recursively runs until `A` is divisible by both `a` and `b` – outputting a dash or pipe based on `a`'s divisibility by `A`.

The function then calls itself, swapping `a` and `b`.

The `S` variable prevents the function from calling itself infinitely.

**Test Cases:**

```js
f=(a,b,S,A=1)=>(A%a?'-':'|')+(A%a|A%b?f(a,b,S,A+1):S?'':`
`+f(b,a,1))

console.log(f(1,1));
console.log(f(1,2));
console.log(f(2,1));
console.log(f(2,2));
console.log(f(6,4));
console.log(f(4,6));
console.log(f(2,3));
console.log(f(3,2));
console.log(f(10,10));
console.log(f(3, 6));
console.log(f(2, 5));
console.log(f(4, 3));
console.log(f(10, 10));
console.log(f(10, 5));
console.log(f(10, 6));
console.log(f(24, 8));
console.log(f(7, 8));
console.log(f(6, 8));
console.log(f(13, 11));
```

---

Previous answers:

## JavaScript (ES8), 91 bytes

```
f=(a,b,i=2,g=(c,d)=>d?g(d,c%d):c)=>i?'|'.padStart(a,'-').repeat(b/g(a,b))+`
`+f(b,a,i-1):''
```

Uses the algorithms:

```
lcm(a, b) = ab / gcd(a, b)
gcd(c, d) = d ? gcd(d, c%d) : c
```

Recursively calls itself just once to output the second line.

**Test Cases:**

```js
f=(a,b,i=2,g=(c,d)=>d?g(d,c%d):c)=>i?'|'.padStart(a,'-').repeat(b/g(a,b))+`
`+f(b,a,i-1):''

console.log(f(1,1));
console.log(f(1,2));
console.log(f(2,1));
console.log(f(2,2));
console.log(f(6,4));
console.log(f(4,6));
console.log(f(2,3));
console.log(f(3,2));
console.log(f(10,10));
console.log(f(3, 6));
console.log(f(2, 5));
console.log(f(4, 3));
console.log(f(10, 10));
console.log(f(10, 5));
console.log(f(10, 6));
console.log(f(24, 8));
console.log(f(7, 8));
console.log(f(6, 8));
console.log(f(13, 11));
```

## JavaScript (ES6), 93 bytes

```
f=(a,b,i=2,g=(c,d)=>!d=>d?c:g(d,c%d):c)=>i?('-'.repeat(a-1)+'|').repeat(a*bb/g(a,b)/a)+`
`+f(b,a,i-1):''
```

Same algorithm as before, using `repeat` instead of `padStart`.

Comment: I thought `padStart` was ES8?

Comment: ```f=(a,b,A=1)=>(A%a?'-':'|')+(A%a|A%b?f(a,b,A+1):a<0?'':`\n`+f(-b,a))```

Comment: @l4m2, I can barely understand code that I wrote a year ago, but it does look like yours does shave off some bytes, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

Assumes `⎕IO←0`. Takes A,B as right argument. **Bonus:** handles input list of any length!

```apl
{'|-'[⌽×⍵∘.|⍳∧/⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/32cfYF0tXqNrnr0o569h6c/6t36qGOGXs2j3s2POpbrA7mxtf9ByhSMFEy5QLSJgjGYNjQAIhjLFMYwAzOMTBQswAxzKG0GpQ2NFQwNIUoUjBVMAQ)

`{`…`}` anonymous lambda where `⍵` represents the right argument

`'|-'[`…`]` index the string with:

`∧/` LCM across the input

`⍳` first that many **ɩ**ntegers (0 through N-1)

`⍵∘.|` division remainder table with the input vertically and that horizontally

`×` signum

`⌽` flip horizontally

Comment: What does that first assumption mean?

Comment: @HelkaHomba It means that arrays index starting at 0, a default on APL interpreters, I believe.

Comment: @HelkaHomba Since APL systems come in both 0-based and 1-based flavours, I just write the assumption. Otherwise one would have to have two APLs. E.g. [ngn/apl can run this very same code](https://ngn.github.io/apl/web/index.html#code=LCM%u2190%7B%27%7C-%27%5B%u233D%D7%u2375%u2218.%7C%u2373%u2227/%u2375%5D%7D%0A%u2191LCM%A8%282%205%29%284%203%29%2810%2010%29%2810%205%29%2810%206%29%2824%208%29%287%208%29%286%208%29%2813%2011%29%282%203%205%29) without specifying `⎕IO←0`, as that is the default there.

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 98 bytes

```
print((a to a*b).find(l=>l%a+l%b==0).map(l=>("-"*(a-1)+"|")*(l/a)+"\n"+("-"*(b-1)+"|")*(l/b)).get)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TclBCsIwEEDRvacYAoWZhEbdiJsIHsAbuJlpo0RiGtoggnr2WHXj7vH/1HHkOsjFdwUOHBL4e/Gpn2CfMzwWN47A4GDzlcza1jyGVBAZygCshewppB6j28WGTWzEuRXZK@dPQtUqjdyuyainIo1xyTOPSZnfkv8lRPbsC9VXfQM)

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! This looks like a great first answer, so +1 from me. I'm not sure, since I've never programmed in Scala, but can `*(a-1)` be golfed to `*~-a` and `*(b-1)` to `*~-b`? Also, could you perhaps add a [TIO link](https://tio.run/#) with test code? (Oh, and that avatar doesn't seem very cubic to me. ;p)

Comment: Thanks! The trick with `*~-a` is great, but unfortunately Scala requires more brackets: `*(~(-a))` to make clear that the concatenations `*~-`, `*~`, `~-` are not fancy function names. I added a TIO link.

Comment: Ah yes, `~-` can be function names in Scala. I remember someone mentioning that before quite a while ago. That's unfortunate regarding golfing. Again welcome, and nice first answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>125</s> <s>118</s> 117 bytes

```java
a->b->{String A="\n",B=A,t="|";for(int i=1;!A.endsWith(t)|!B.endsWith(t);B+=i++%b<1?t:"-")A+=i%a<1?t:"-";return A+B;}
```

-7 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*.
-1 byte by starting with a trailing new-line (`A="",B="\n"` replaced with `A="\n",B=A`).

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jZLfa4MwEMff91dcAwXFKLW/Npbq0IfBHgaDPuxh20O0aZfORtGzUNr@7TZSBx1EGERy@fjN3X09t3zP3bwQarv6adKMVxW8cqmOdwAVcpQpbLXCq1Fm3rpWKcpcec9dsHhRKDaipP8TLbGUahOGkEIADXfDxA2PVwhRQD4VoXEQUQzIibB1XlpSIcjAZ4PIE2pVvUv8ttA@DeLbI4udQDrOMFn4T/hIXGJHGgz575GVAutSQeTE7NwwbUyvok4y7a2zuM/lCnbatnXt5uMLuN1@Ai3Ut/HwpilaPgXfZiY8NuCxWT02q@cUpgY8pTA3J5kY8MSce9KbZGYuacrtj7SfUc@LWQ83ltUFHgz83oznZuy3w7j2ee5GWso9R/Fnprc32p@JU2i3pBvu8lCh2Hl5jV7RajJlcXCAANOPo2WsT5Z6vCiyg8XtLkjsfnHX5bm5AA)

```java
a->b->{             // Method with two integer parameters and String return-type
  String A="\n",    //  String top line (starting with a trailing new-line)
         B=A,       //  String bottom-line (starting with a new-line)
         t="|";     //  Temp String "|" which is used multiple times
  for(int i=1;      //  Index-integer, starting at 1
      !A.endsWith(t)|!B.endsWith(t);
                    //  Loop as long as both Strings aren't ending with "|"
      B+=           //    After every iteration: append `B` with:
         i++%b<1?   //     If `i` is divisible by `b`:
                    //     (and increase `i` by 1 in the process)
          t         //      `t` (holding "|")
         :          //     Else:
          "-")      //      A literal "-"
    A+=             //   Append `A` with:
       i%a<1?       //    If `i` is divisible by `a`
        t           //     `t` (holding "|")
       :            //    Else:
        "-";        //     A literal "-"
                    //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
  return A+B;       //  Return both lines, separated by the new-line `B` started with
}                   // End of method
```

Comment: 118 bytes: `a->b->{String A="",B="\n",k="|";for(int i=0;!A.endsWith(k)|!B.endsWith(k);B+=i%b<1?k:"-")A+=++i%a<1?k:"-";return A+B;}`

Comment: @Nevay Thanks. Can't believe I missed the most obvious thing `!A.endsWith(t)|!B.endsWith(t)` when I was looking for a short way to check whether both are ending with `|`.. And starting B with a new-line instead of putting it between them at the return is also smart.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 103 bytes

```java
a->b->{String l="",r="|\n";for(int m=0;(++m%a|m%b)>0;r+=m%b<1?'|':'-')l+=m%a<1?'|':'-';return l+r+'|';}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZJLa4NAEMfv@RSDEFR8oHm1ZKO9FXroKUfrYU1M2HRdZV0DIfGz21WTVopLRpDxN6/9O3vCZ@zkRcpO@@@mqBJKdrCjuCzhExN2nYC0UmAh8YEwTOEkC9xKEOoeKrYTJGfuBxPvd3/zJLwVnLBjGAKDoMFOmDjhtWdAA02zeaDdvpiGDjk3CBOQBR4yLCub4ls2TczQQ9wKpLfx3/SbvtYd3aQtwH8A8VRUnAG1uCURqptWA5p0Uu4K74rOOdlDJnUavbb@JFEMmB9LE3r1rcmjRLHkIi1FCcEg8rCrb4Nf26N8NsZnivyZIn9lw2KML2xYKfrMx/hc0X@u7rNUzB3t73tSmKeKLFWB8dlyyOtY4EXBVwruS3X@8HfX6NeVVw2MbsHdemHdb9n8t@TtpRRp5uaVcAt5SwRlRpsXeTFYoMnH6uoiPzbRs0Lm4qKgl0cDc/gp6583GGTUk/5dNz8)

#### 110 bytes, n input values

```java
a->{String s="";for(int v:a){for(int i=1,z=1;z>(z=0);s+=i++%v<1?'|':'-')for(int k:a)z|=i%k;s+='\n';}return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJdb4IwFH33V9yYGGhAQv3aYq1729ue9sh46BRNFQuhhUSQ384K6GIWmt0mTXvuuR@ntydWsGmSRuK0Pzdp/h3zHexiJiV8MC6qEWiTiikNH7hgMZx0gJcrHnuHXOwUT4T3fj9suFBB6MKnyrg4biED2rDpturvIOl4TA5JZmsaFGuGqseFU@yWFJNya5fUR0Q6lDvOpNjgN@tmra2phR7Us44rb5RPzi3L@hIWqbNI5ZkASeqmbZeMuq7vYu7NFwnfw0VLsnsZfU9BCCw7SgS90NY6DRpXkVQS6JPnYRV2AdfuID4bwmcG/szAX7mwGMIXLqwMeeZD@NyQf27OszTUHcyPfS3MN3mWJsdwbV3kdcjxYsBXBhxrdfj5uWvye9SfCOxuwN14Yd1PGf0Z8udVqujiJbnyUv1LVCzslhf4ITgw1svp4gIcIvJfYOaxNI2vXQL0RK9H/V43Pw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>96</strike> 88 bytes

**Edit:** Saved 4 bytes thanks to [@Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun)

**Edit:** Saved 4 bytes thanks to [@Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47120/rod)

```python
lambda a,b:b/gcd(a,b)*("-"*~-a+"|")+"\n"+a/gcd(a,b)*("-"*~-b+"|")
from fractions import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zcm7CoAgFADQva@QO/lIgoiGoD9xuSaWkA/MJYh@3aK17cBJZ9li6KudVd3Ra4MEWz3pbl0MfcU4BQn8lijgAiZABRD4W/1tY3P0xGZciovhIM6nmAuvKbtQqKVDOzJWHw)

Comment: [88 bytes](https://tio.run/##Zcm7CoAgFADQva@QO/lIgoiGoD9xuSaWkA/MJYh@3aK17cBJZ9li6KudVd3Ra4MEWz3pbl0MfcU4BQn8lijgAiZABRD4W/1tY3P0xGZciovhIM6nmAuvKbtQqKVDOzJWHw) or 
[77 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBDsIgEADAu68gXApY1BrjwcSXUA7YZnWN7JKVAybGr@NM@dQH07HDde6vlG9rcu0SWsC4vy@rcc06o712P9/C5DFu9VdbYFGokNRhnOIGhLMCSUtFprfCXFiq60WQqhlmGnZPRjJgTuPZWtv/) for a more flexible output

Comment: [88 bytes](https://tio.run/##Zcm7CoAgFADQva@QO/lIgoiGoD9xuSaWkA/MJYh@3aK17cBJZ9li6KudVd3Ra4MEWz3pbl0MfcU4BQn8lijgAiZABRD4W/1tY3P0xGZciovhIM6nmAuvKbtQqKVDOzJWHw)

Comment: Apparently outputting a list of strings isn't acceptable. :I Replace `[...]` with `'\n'.join(...)` to fix.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>66</s> 60 bytes

```hs
a#b=do x<-[a,b];lcm a b`take`cycle(([2..x]>>"-")++"|")++"\n"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E5yTYlX6HCRjc6UScp1jonOVchUSEpoSQxOzUhuTI5J1VDI9pIT68i1s5OSVdJU1tbqQZMxuQp/c9NzMxTsFUoKC0JLilSUDm0wNBA2ew/AA)

Same length:

```hs
a#b=unlines[take(lcm a b)$cycle$([2..x]>>"-")++"|"|x<-[a,b]]
```

Old solution:

```hs
l!x=[1..div l x]>>([2..x]>>"-")++"|"
a#b|l<-lcm a b=l!a++'\n':l!b
```

Comment: You can save a byte with `'\n':`.

Comment: @Laikoni Careful, I am closing in on you

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 89 bytes

*Not the shortest Python 2 entry, but a different approach than* `gcd` *which may still be golfable.*

```python
a,b=input()
h,p='-|'
x=b*(h*~-a+p),a*(h*~-b+p)
for v in x:print v[~zip(*x).index((p,p)):]
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1EnyTYzr6C0REOTK0OnwFZdt0adq8I2SUsjQ6tON1G7QFMnEcJOArK50vKLFMoUMvMUKqwKijLzShTKouuqMgs0tCo09TLzUlIrNDQKdAo0Na1i//830zEBAA)**

Answer (score 2):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 131 bytes

```
> Input
> Input
>> 1⊔2
>> (3]
>> L∣1
>> L∣2
>> Each 5 4
>> Each 6 4
> '-|'
>> 9ⁿL
>> Each 10 7
>> Each 10 8
>> Output 11 12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hAtO2ykYPuqaYgRiaBjHgiifRx2LDWEMsIRrYnKGgqmCCZxtBmIrqOvWqIOELB817veByxkaKJgjcyxAHP/SEqBtCoaGCoZARxgacJkBAA)

### How it works

If you're unfamiliar with Whispers' program structure, I'd recommend reading the first part of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174898/66833) post.

In this explanation, we'll refer to the two inputs as \$x\$ and \$y\$ respectively. Our first two lines simply take the inputs in, and store them on lines **1** (\$x\$) and **2** (\$y\$). We then move to line **3**, which returns \$\alpha = \mathrm{lcm}(x, y)\$ and to line **4**, which returns the range \$A = [1, 2, ..., \alpha]\$.

Next, we reach our first two `Each` statements, operating on each of the inputs:

```
>> L∣1
>> L∣2
>> Each 5 4
>> Each 6 4
```

These four lines both operate on \$A\$, but return two different arrays, which we will call \$A_x\$ and \$A_y\$. While being different arrays, they are both formed in similar ways, as can be noted from the similarities in the two pairs of lines. In fact, we can define \$A_x\$ and \$A_y\$ as

$$A_x := [(i \div x) \in \mathbb{Z} \: | \: i \in A]$$
$$A_y := [(i \div y) \in \mathbb{Z} \: | \: i \in A]$$

This leaves us with two lists consisting of a \$1\$ where we'd expect there to be a `|` character, and a \$0\$ where there should be a `-`. This takes us to the next section of our code:

```
> '-|'
>> 9ⁿL
>> Each 10 7
>> Each 10 8
```

First, we yield the string `-|`, then we create our next two arrays \$B_x\$ and \$B_y\$. Helpfully, we can use the same function to map \$A_x\$ to \$B_x\$ and \$A_y\$ to \$B_y\$, namely `9ⁿL`. This function yields the \$n^{th}\$ element of the string on line **9** i.e. `-|`, where \$n\$ is either \$0\$ or \$1\$, depending on the element from the respective \$A\$ arrays. This yields the two arrays \$B_x\$ and \$B_y\$ as defined below:

$$(B_x)_i = 
\begin{cases}
\text{"-"}, & (A_x)_i = 0 \\
\text{"|"}, & (A_x)_i = 1
\end{cases}$$

$$(B_y)_i =
\begin{cases}
\text{"-"}, & (A_y)_i = 0 \\
\text{"|"}, & (A_y)_i = 1
\end{cases}$$

The `Each` command is special-cased for when yielding an array of strings, where it returns a single string, rather than an array. Finally, we reach the statement

```
>> Output 11 12
```

which outputs \$B_x\$, then a newline, then \$B_y\$

Comment: I believe `…` is one byte shorter than `Each`, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hAtO2ykYPuqaYgQUMARxfB51LIYzjECMRw3LFEwUjBVMkTlmQPXqujXqIDHLR437fUAM18TkDAVDAwVzZI4FiONfWgK0TMHQUMEQ6AZDAy4zAA "Whispers v2 – Try It Online"), though I can't shake the feeling that there's some way to combine the processes

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>19</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
2{H┌*┐+..*..g/mP
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=MiU3QkgldTI1MEMqJXUyNTEwKy4uKi4uZy9tUA__,inputs=MTMlMEExMQ__)

Explanation:

```
2{                two times do
  H                 decreate ToS - input - by 1
   ┌*               get that many dashes
     ┐+             append a vertical bar
       ..*          push both inputs multiplied           \
          ..g       push gcd(input1, input2)              | LCM - 7 bytes :/
             /      divide the multiblication by the GCD  /
              m     mold the string to that length
               P    print that in a new line
```

Comment: You documented before implementing? o0

Comment: @icrieverytim SOGL has many, _many_ documentated things that aren't implemented. :p The documentation is basically my TODO list (which I rarely do :p)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>121</s> <s>99</s> <s>93</s> <s>92</s> 89 bytes

This should be much shorter, hmmmm....

```c
#define L(x)for(j=-1,i=a;j<i;i+=i%b||i%a)putchar(++j?j%x?45:124:10);
i,j;f(a,b){L(a)L(b)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYxBCsIwFET3OUWpBP4nKdgau2gMvUAvkcZGf8AqVaHQ9uwxgltn9YY3jCsuzsW4Ow@exiHrYEZ/nyCYopRkrA4n0iQM8X5diVt8vF/uaicQIrSBz606NmWlmnKPmpEM2oOVPS4dWOygxy3eLI2AbGFZiodaqrT8cnp6Qp7/mgcl6z@mkofEG4sf)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 20 bytes

```
'-|'{~*.$&>;&(<:=i.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/9V1a9Sr67T0VNTsrNU0bKxsM/U0/2tyKekpqKfZWqkr6CjUWimkFXNxpSZn5CuYKaQpmPwHAA)

Comment: this is pretty J

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <strike>64</strike> 57 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{[a,b].map{|n|(1..a.lcm(b)).map{|x|x%n>0??-:?|}*''}}
```

-7 bytes thanks to G B.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/JCoNAEETvfkVfklHRwXFLEKIfIhJcieBGRsHg@O3GSZukD/2qquvSzyl7bdVtM8PUyJZ4Xwlt02ERnVAZpSlt8lbNNA3DWcynLrSiyAwiseqErOsWEwaMGLDDlrDR2eh8cCVc8DF0JBy8Od/Qw8rnxixg1iG8g1hz4Sp5QfgI5gBjJKFlmj@g6EFwocA@wzRy4H9ZxTqnfGjqUX6inoOxv9da8isoZVdsbw)

Comment: You don't need to include the 'puts', if the function returns 2 strings it's ok. And you can make it shorter by using the array * operator (array*'' is equivalent to array.join)

Comment: @GB thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
ＮθＮη≔θζＷ﹪ζη≦⁺θζＥ⟦θη⟧…⁺×-⁻ι¹|ζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYs9C8IwFAD3/opHpvcgAbu4dHIUbOngJg61jSaQJm3SKBT/e4wfg@Mdd73qfO86k9LeTnFp4niRHmeqin9WmXch6JvFmcOa6aG0kYC1G6JxuHJQRFB307c6yOuCrYmBw69vvbYL5gBP2agzh9qZ4dPgUY8yIBMsS22z0BxKIg7syei9E1UplZtim8Q9iWBe) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @ASCII-only.

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##TYu9DoIwFEZ3nuKm071Jm8jiwuRoIoTBzTggVNuktNBSTYjvXuvP4HjOd75edb53nUlpb6e4NHG8SI8zVcU/q8y7EPTN4sxhzfRQ2kjA2g3ROFw5KCKou@lbHeR1wdbEAL@89doumHc8ZaPOHGpnhk@CRz3KgEywLLXNQnMoiTiwJ6P3nahKqdwU2yTuSQTzAg)

Comment: @ASCII-only Something new to document!

Comment: Thanks for documenting! (sorry, I don't really feel like documenting things although I should *really* do it), if you don't mind there's some more to document https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=40270513#40270513 https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=40270838#40270838 (not sure where the directional casts should go, they're not commands nor are they operators)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), <s>42</s> 38 bytes

```
[:...lcm@z:[:z\/\#-'-'*\rep'|'+out]"!]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/P9pKT08vJznXocoq2qoqRj9GWVddV10rpii1QL1GXTu/tCRWSTH2v4NVGheXhpmCiaZCGpeGsYIRmDZSMAbThgqGUBomDuUbKBgaAFn/AQ)

Input in the form of a pair of numbers. All the test cases put together look kinda like buildings.

### Explanation

This first takes the `lcm` of the two input numbers into `z`. Then, for each number `k`, we generate `z / k` strings of `-` of length `k - 1`, adding `|` to the end of each, and outputting each.

### Previous counted attempts

42 bytes: `` [:...lcm@z:[:z\/\#-'-'*\rep'|'+''#`out]"!] ``

### Other attempts

43 bytes: `` [:...lcm@z:[:z\/\#-'-'*\rep'|'#`'|'+out]"!] ``

45 bytes: `` ['@lcm'!#~@z,[:z\/\#-'-'*\rep'|'#`'|'+out]"!] ``

45 bytes: `` [:...lcm@x[x'-'*\#<$betailmap'|'#`'|'+out]"!] ``

53 bytes: `[:...lcm'-'*@z#-'.'*'('\+')'+'.'+[z\'$1|'repl out]"!]`

54 bytes: `` [:...lcm@x{!x'-'*('('n#-'.'*').')''#`'$1|'repl out}"!] ``

Answer (score 1):

**VBA (Excel) , <strike>144</strike>  142 bytes**

```
Sub q()
a=[a1]
b=[a2]
Do Until c=d And d="|"
e=e+1
c=IIf(e Mod a,"-","|")
d=IIf(e Mod b,"-","|")
f=f& c
g=g& d
Loop
Debug.? f& vbCr& g
End Sub
```

-2 bytes. thanks Sir  Washington Guedes.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 89

```js
f=(a,b,t=`
`,l=0,R=n=>'-'.repeat(n-1)+'|')=>l||1/t?f(a,b,l<0?t+R(b,l+=b):R(a,l-=a)+t,l):t
```

Evaluating the LCM with repeated addictions.

*Less golfed*

```js
F=(a,b, sa='', sb='', la=0, lb=0)=>
{
    var R=n=>'-'.repeat(n-1)+'|'
    if (la != lb || la == 0)
    {
        if (la < lb) {
            sa += R(a)
            la += a
        }
        else
        {
            sb += R(b)
            lb += b
        }
        return F(a, b, sa, sb, la, lb)
    }
    else
        return sa+'\n'+sb
}
```

**Test**

```js
f=(a,b,t=`
`,l=0,R=n=>'-'.repeat(n-1)+'|')=>l||1/t?f(a,b,l<0?t+R(b,l+=b):R(a,l-=a)+t,l):t

function update()
{
  var [a,b]=I.value.match(/\d+/g)
  R.textContent = f(+a,+b)
}  

update()
```

```html
<input id=I oninput='update()' value='4 6'>
<pre id=R></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 20 bytes

```
*./($'-|'#~<:,1:)"0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0FLT19DRV23Rl25zsZKx9BKU8kg9n9qcka@QpqCoZGCpYKxgpECF1hAXR1Ca6QpGWoqGCoY6gAJIx2gPIhlAERgylTHSsHQWMHQ8D8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 77 Bytes

Anonymous worksheet formula that takes input from range `A1:B1` and outputs to the calling cell

```
=REPT(REPT("-",A1-1)&"|",LCM(1:1)/A1)&"
"&REPT(REPT("-",B1-1)&"|",LCM(1:1)/B1
```

-4 Bytes thanks to [@EngineerToast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38183/engineer-toast)

Comment: Can you presume that the nothing else is input to row 1? If so, you can shorted `LCM(A1,B1)` to just `LCM(1:1)` to save 4 bytes. I think it's reasonable to presume a blank starting sheet and specify where both the inputs and formula are.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 79 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from the range `[A1:B1]` and outputs a visualization of their LCM to the VBE immediate window.

<sub>*This is a port of my [Google Sheets answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144423/61846).*</sub>

```vb
?[Rept(Rept("-",A1-1)&"|",LCM(1:1)/A1)]:?[Rept(Rept("-",B1-1)&"|",LCM(1:1)/B1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```
£×/Ury)î|ù-X
```

[Japt Interpreter](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=o9cvVXJ5Ke58+S1Y&input=WzcsOF0KLVI=)

Inputs as an array of numbers. Outputs as an array of strings. The -R flag slightly improves how the output looks, but isn't necessary for the logic.

Explanation:

```
£              For each of the two inputs as X, print...
        |           The string "|"
         ù-X        Left-padded with "-" until it is X characters long
       î            Repeated until its length is
 ×/Ury)             The Least Common Multiple
```

Extra thanks to Shaggy for finding some bytes to save.

Comment: [15 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=o9cvVXJ5Ke4tcFggaHxK&input=WzcsOF0KLVI=)

Comment: @Shaggy Interesting, I never thought to use that part of Japt in that exact way.

Comment: [Knocked another few bytes off](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=o9cvVXJ5Ke58+S1Y&input=WzcsOF0KLVI=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
,ḍþælị⁾|-ZY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/n4Y7ew/sOL8t5uLv7UeO@Gt2oyP@Hl@s/alqTBeQe2nZo2///0YY6hrE6CkDKCEQZQXhGEJ6ZjgmIMtExgwgagyhjiJwxTNAUogQsZ2igY2gAZZhCaYgyEx0LEG0OocwglKGxjqFhLAA)

### How it works

```
,ḍþælị⁾|-ZY - Main link. Takes A on the left and B on the right
,           - Pair; [A, B]
   æl       - LCM; L := LCM(A, B)
  þ         - Create a 2×L matrix and for each cell (i,j) i ∈ (A,B), 1 ≤ j ≤ L:
 ḍ          -   Is i divisible by j?
     ị⁾|-   - Index into "|-", replacing 1 with "|" and 0 with "-"
         Z  - Transpose the matrix into a L×2 matrix
          Y - Join by newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 20 bytes

```
j.e*/@QtkiFQ+*\-tb\|
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j.e%2a%2F%40QtkiFQ%2B%2a%5C-tb%5C%7C&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=6%2C+4%0A1%2C+1&debug=0).

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 67 bytes

```
\d+
$*-
^((-+)(\2)*) ((\2)+)$
$1$#5$*1¶$4$#3$*11
-1
|
+`(-*.)1
$1$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYo7DgIxDER7n8LSGikfBe3ESUBcgEus0CJBQUOBtuRcHICLBYdi5j2P/Lpvj@e179zpvPblFklCootzKXq3ZB88u8HohQQyVQn4fqTIpGagBHpTXF0Ke4/xgd7BIHCmbMzGxoUKN3MltVv/Xm1TwsyYR9dRthc@0sHSLFAGfg) Link includes test cases.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 142 bytes

```
list(,$a,$b)=$argv;for($n=$a;$n<=$a*$b;$n+=$a)if($n%$b==0)break;while($i<$n)echo++$i%$a==0?'|':'-';echo"
";while($j<$n)echo++$j%$b==0?'|':'-';
```

[Try it online !](https://eval.in/868259)

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript (ES6), 84 bytes

```
f=(a,b,c=1,o=x='-'.repeat(a-1)+'|')=>(o.length%b?f(a,b,0,o+x):o)+(c?`
`+f(b,a,0):'')
```

Test Cases:

```js
f=(a,b,c=1,o=x='-'.repeat(a-1)+'|')=>(o.length%b?f(a,b,0,o+x):o)+(c?`
`+f(b,a,0):'')

console.log(f(1,1));
console.log(f(1,2));
console.log(f(2,1));
console.log(f(2,2));
console.log(f(6,4));
console.log(f(4,6));
console.log(f(2,3));
console.log(f(3,2));
console.log(f(10,10));
console.log(f(3, 6));
console.log(f(2, 5));
console.log(f(4, 3));
console.log(f(10, 10));
console.log(f(10, 5));
console.log(f(10, 6));
console.log(f(24, 8));
console.log(f(7, 8));
console.log(f(6, 8));
console.log(f(13, 11));
```

### Old answer Javascript (ES6), 91 bytes

```
f=(a,b)=>{for(x=y='',i=0;!i++||q||r;)q=i%a,r=i%b,x+=q?'-':'|',y+=r?'-':'|';return x+'\n'+y}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 80 bytes

```
{for(;++m%$1||m%$2;)for(i=0;i++<2;)r[i]=r[i](m%$i?"-":"|");$0=r[1]"|\n"r[2]"|"}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMNaWztXVcWwpgZIGllrgoQybQ2sM7W1bYDcoujMWFsQoQGUzrRX0lWyUqpR0rRWMQCKGsYq1cTkKRVFGwEZSrWG//8bGioYGgMA)

For 2 or more values you can use the following 94 bytes:

```
{m=0;for(x=1;x&&++m;)for(x=i=0;i++<NF;){x+=r=m%$i;R[i]=R[i](r?"-":"|")}for(;++z<i;)print R[z]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/OtfWwDotv0ijwtbQukJNTVs711oTws8EymRqa9v4uVlrVldo2xbZ5qqqZFoHRWfG2oIIjSJ7JV0lK6UaJc1akA5rbe0qm0xrzYKizLwShaDoqtja//8NDRUMjQE)

I'm probably missing something obvious to shorten this. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{[a,b].map{|x|(?-*~-x+?|)*(a.lcm(b)/x)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6k6GkjE6uUmFlTXVNRo2Otq1elWaNvXaGppJOrlJOdqJGnqV2jW1v4vKC0pVkiLNtVRMDSM1Y5WV4/VTos2NNMxNIr9DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>85</s> 82 bytes

```
for([,$a,$b]=$argv;++$i%$a|$y=$i%$b;$t.="-|"[!$y])$s.=$i%$a?"-":"|";echo"$s|
$t|";
```

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d056944c0115ed044644ccf2ddcaa99cac81ceb4).

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 39 bytes

```perl6
{@^a>>.&{('-'x$_-1~'|')x([lcm] @a)/$_}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv9ohLtHOTk@tWkNdV71CJV7XsE69Rl2zQiM6Jzk3VsEhUVNfJb629r9ecWKlQlp@kUKaRrSxjlGspjUXspCFjjm6kJGJjgW6mKGxjqEhUPA/AA)

Takes input as a pair of numbers and returns a list of lines. Note that you can pass in as many integers as you like and it will print the `lcm` graph of all of them.

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 79 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)do{$x+='-|'[!($c=++$i%$a)];$y+='-|'[!($d=$i%$b)]}while($c+$d)
$x;$y
```

Ungolfed test script:

```powershell
$f = {

param($a,$b)
do{
    $x+='-|'[!($c=++$i%$a)]
    $y+='-|'[!($d=$i%$b)]
}while($c+$d)
$x;$y

}

@(
    ,(1,1,"| |")
    ,(1,2,"|| -|")
    ,(2,1,"-| ||")
    ,(6,4,"-----|-----| ---|---|---|")
    ,(4,6,"---|---|---| -----|-----|")
    ,(2,3,"-|-|-| --|--|")
    ,(3,2,"--|--| -|-|-|")
    ,(3,6,"--|--| -----|")
    ,(2,5,"-|-|-|-|-| ----|----|")
    ,(4,3,"---|---|---| --|--|--|--|")
    ,(10,10,"---------| ---------|")
    ,(10,5,"---------| ----|----|")
    ,(10,6,"---------|---------|---------| -----|-----|-----|-----|-----|")
    ,(24,8,"-----------------------| -------|-------|-------|")
    ,(7,8,"------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------| -------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|")
    ,(6,8,"-----|-----|-----|-----| -------|-------|-------|")
    ,(13,11,"------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------| ----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|")
) | % {
    $a,$b,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $a $b
    "$(""$result"-eq"$expected"): $a,$b"
    $result
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: 1,1
|
|
True: 1,2
||
-|
True: 2,1
-|
||
True: 6,4
-----|-----|
---|---|---|
True: 4,6
---|---|---|
-----|-----|
True: 2,3
-|-|-|
--|--|
True: 3,2
--|--|
-|-|-|
True: 3,6
--|--|
-----|
True: 2,5
-|-|-|-|-|
----|----|
True: 4,3
---|---|---|
--|--|--|--|
True: 10,10
---------|
---------|
True: 10,5
---------|
----|----|
True: 10,6
---------|---------|---------|
-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
True: 24,8
-----------------------|
-------|-------|-------|
True: 7,8
------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
True: 6,8
-----|-----|-----|-----|
-------|-------|-------|
True: 13,11
------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>52</s> 47 bytes

```julia
p->println.(@.("-"^(p-1)*"|").^(lcm(p...).÷p))
```

Anonymous function; takes a list or tuple of two integers and prints the ASCII-art. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifpmCr8L9A166gKDOvJCdPT8NBT0NJVylOo0DXUFNLqUZJUy9OIyc5V6NAT09PU@/w9gJNzf9pGtFmOiaxmv8B)

#### Explanation

```
p->                 Function of p (a list or tuple of two integers):
 println.(   )       Print with newline, vectorized:
  @.(   )             Vectorize throughout the following expression:
    "-"^(p-1)*"|"      String of x-1 hyphens and one pipe for each x in p
   (   ).^(   )        each repeated this many times:
      lcm(p...)         LCM of the two integers in p
               .÷p      divided by each number in p
```

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifpmCr8L9A185Br6AoM68kJ09DQ0lXKa5Ot0BLqUZJM05DJSc5V6NA8/D2Ak3N/2ka0WY6JrGa/wE)