# Help me with my polyrhythms

Tags: code-golf

I'm a musician, and I need more polyrhythms in my life!

A polyrhythm occurs in music (and in nature) when two events (claps, notes, fireflies flashing etc.) are occurring at two different regular intervals. The two kinds of event happen a different number of times in the same interval.

If I tap with my left hand twice, and with my right hand 3 times, in the same space of time, it looks a little bit like this:

```
  ------
R . . .
L .  .
```

The hyphens at the top denote the length of the polyrthmic pattern, which is the lowest common multiple or 2 and 3. This can be understood as the point at which the pattern repeats.

There's also a 'metarhythm', which is the pattern produced when either hand is tapping:

```
  ------
R . . .
L .  .  
M . ...
```

This is a simple, and very common polyrhythm, with a ratio of 3:2.

Let's just say I don't want to do a simple polyrhythm that I can work out in my head, so I need something to work it out for me. I could do it long-form on paper, or...

---

Rules:

- Write some code to generate and display a polyrhythm diagram, as described above.
- Any old language, try for the fewest bytes.
- Your code takes two arguments:

  - Number of taps with the Left hand (positive integer)
  - Number of taps with the right hand (positive integer)
- It will work out the length, which is the lowest common multiple for the two arguments.
- The top line will consist of two whitespace characters followed by hyphens displaying the length (length * '-')
- The second and third lines will show the pattern for the right and left hands:

  - It will start with an R or L, do denote which hand it is, followed by a space.
  - The interval for that hand is the length divided by it's argument.
  - The taps will start at the third character, denoted by any character you choose. From then on it will display the same character 'interval' characters apart.
  - It will not be longer than the length line.
- The fourth line is the metarhythm:

  - It will start with an upper case M, followed by a space.
  - From the third character onwards, it will show a character (any character you choose) in every position where there's a tap on either the right or the left hand.
- Trailing whitespace is irrelevant.

---

Test cases:

r = 3, l = 2

```
  ------
R . . .
L .  .  
M . ...
```

r = 4, l = 3

```
  ------------
R .  .  .  .    
L .   .   .    
M .  .. . ..
```

r = 4, l = 5

```
  --------------------
R .    .    .    .                     
L .   .   .   .   .      
M .   ..  . . .  ..
```

r = 4, l = 7

```
  ----------------------------
R .      .      .      .      
L .   .   .   .   .   .   .   
M .   .  ..   . . .   ..  .
```

r = 4, l = 8

```
  --------
R . . . . 
L ........
M ........
```

---

Happy golfing!

Comment: Your test cases include lots of trailing whitespace, can we omit them/add more?

Comment: Do we have to accept `r` and `l` as two separate values? Could we accept a two-element array instead, for example? How about the order of them, is that strictly `r` followed by `l`?

Comment: @Sok That's acceptable as an interpretation of 'two arguments'

Comment: Does it need to actually print the diagram out, or can it simply return it?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard returning is fine.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as [Illustrate the Lowest Common Multiple](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/143725/76162), but with an extra line?

Comment: @JoKing it’s similar, the combined line is a different challenge, tho.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 131 bytes

Outputs `0` as the *tap* character.

```javascript
r=>l=>`  ${g=n=>n?s.replace(/./g,(_,x)=>[,a=x%(k/r),x%=k/l,a*x][n]&&' '):++k%l|k%r?'-'+g():`-
`,s=g(k=0)}R ${g(1)}L ${g(2)}M `+g(3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc3NCoJAFAXgfU/hIp25OWq/FMLVF6hNW5EcTIeaYZQxYqB8drN2gbvDdw6cO3/yrjS39hHo5loNNQ4GE4VJ4Tjzl0CNiU670FSt4mVFozASjF6YBUwyxtG6VEYGmHVRRorxhc0znXsecQjEvi9d9ZauSUlAfEEhLoJZwToUVOIS@vP3ga6gP/7CGvqTU4y7DQxlo7tGVaFqBK1HGEuY/eMWRp/A3RTup/AAMHwA)

#### How?

We use the same helper function \$g()\$ for two different purposes.

When \$g()\$ is called with no argument or an argument equal to \$0\$, it recursively builds the hyphen string of length \$k=\operatorname{lcm}(l,r)\$ with a trailing linefeed:

```javascript
g = _ => ++k % l | k % r ? '-' + g() : `-\n`
```

This string is saved in \$s\$.

When \$g()\$ is called with \$1 \le n \le 3\$, it generates a *tap* string by replacing each hyphen at position \$x\$ in \$s\$ with either a space or \$0\$:

```javascript
g = n => s.replace(/./g, (_, x) => [, a = x % (k / r), x %= k / l, a * x][n] && ' ')
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>187</s> <s>185</s> <s>183</s> <s>174</s> <s>166</s> <s>156</s> <s>148</s> <s>147</s> 145 bytes

Uses `-` as the tap character

```python
a,b=r,l=input()
while b:a,b=b,a%b
w=r*l/a
for x,y,z in zip(' RLM',(w,r,l,r),(w,r,l,l)):print x,''.join('- '[i%(w/y)!=0<i%(w/z)]for i in range(w))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5RC4IwFIXf769YgmyTW4YmhbSn6q0Ieo0etrBcyJRhTP3zNoUePjhczv04Td@WtUnGw/V4EkEQjBKVsFgJbZpvyzi4UlcFUfl0VyhDBU7YqIolvGpLOuxxINqQQTeMktv5QpE59AK0/J8qzvPGatP6OqWrT60No0tC7zpkLu75Qqz3cxz4Y5LqSWileRfMcT7Or@C3ARRd8STT1CgbU0xgg6kn82w9O/gB)

---

Saved:

- -2 bytes, thanks to Jonathan Frech

Comment: `[i%(w/y)and i%(w/z)>0]` could be `[i%(w/y)!=0<i%(w/z)]`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

## Java 11, <s>226</s> <s>234</s> <s>233</s> 219 bytes

```java
String h(int r,int l,int m){var s="";for(;m>0;)s+=m%r*(m--%l)<1?'.':32;return s;}

r->l->{int a=r,b=l,m;for(;b>0;b=a%b,a=m)m=b;m=r*l/a;return"  "+repeat("-",m)+"\nR "+h(m/r,m+1,m)+"\nL "+h(m/l,m+1,m)+"\nM "+h(m/r,m/l,m);}
```

Kind of lengthy; too bad Java does not have an `lcm()` function. Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##jVLLbtswEDzLX7EQYFiMHo7iAg2qUL0VaNFcmmPaA2XTlhySEpYrA4ahb3cpmU2KHOoeRC2Hs8/ZvTiIdL95OXd9pZo1rJWwFh5FY@A0CzxoSZD7HdpmA9o9RU@Ejdk9/wKBO8tGZrB3gbKeGpVte7OmpjXZF288fDUkdxIT@C/SJXhZwhY4nDEtVVqeGkMgOCYVV4kuti1GRVXeFhUX8yoRXDPNq0JzvFFLUaCkHk0IEMYoOykoCtMw0SwOf5ofDqwjvcREx7nHvntM/YU9vvFGnBXDOQgK1@jT0ZLUWdtT1rlCSZlom4muU8fojnljxdgV6oq9@lyjfvhD/XiV@lrA/UQdZu8lvMwW/FT8zSYwjtc4IWG5BNtXlhrqSYKbM3xzmkGeL6x3zryzc2FjNT6i0yoMx/ImbcCkKZRwW8BlOwKEmIMd3wf3XQQC/FeN9ZgBMBlPNZ2anQ4CwXKXaMqi3QYwG3M9x5tIp@lcsYf88yJbfFrd@SVwOYexqVqqTiJoSXW7mfpypsD6SLV2/d/nUB1J2tlw/g0) (TIO does not have Java 11 yet, so this uses a helper method instead of `String.repeat()`).

My initial version took the interval between taps instead of the number of taps. Fixed now. Thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for golfing 1 byte.

Ungolfed:

```java
String h(int r, int l, int m) { // helper function returning a line of metarhythm; parameters are: tap interval (right hand), tap interval (left hand), length
    var s = ""; // start with an empty String
    for(; m > 0; ) // repeat until the length is reached
        s += m % r * (m-- % l) < 1 ? '.' : 32; // if at least one of the hands taps, add a dot, otherwise add a space (ASCII code 32 is ' ')
    return s; // return the constructed line
}

r -> l -> { // lambda taking two integers in currying syntax and returning a String
    int a = r, b = l, m; // duplicate the inputs
    for(; b > 0; b = a % b, a = m) // calculate the GCD of r,l using Euclid's algorithm:
        m=b; // swap and replace one of the inputs by the remainder of their division; stop once it hits zero
    m = r * l / a; // calculate the length: LCM of r,l using a=GCD(r,l)
    return // build and return the output:
    "  " + "-".repeat(m) // first line, m dashes preceded by two spaces
    + "\nR " + h(m / r, m + 1, m) // second line, create the right-hand rhythm; by setting l = m + 1 for a metarhythm, we ensure there will be no left-hand taps
    + "\nL " + h(m / l, m + 1, m) // third line, create the left-hand rhythm the same way; also note that we pass the tap interval instead of the number of taps
    + "\nM " + h(m / r, m / l, m); // fourth line, create  the actual metarhythm
}
```

Comment: It's not much, but -1 byte by changing `?".":" "` to `?'.':32`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Every byte counts :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>185 228 223 234</s> 249 bytes

```python
def f(r,l):
     c='.';d=' ';M,R,L=[r*l*[d]for _ in d*3]
     for i in range(r*l):
      if i%r<1:L[i]=M[i]=c
      if i%l<1:R[i]=M[i]=c
      if r<R.count(c)and l<L.count(c):R[i]=L[i]=M[i]=d;break
     print d,i*'-','\nR',''.join(R),'\nL',''.join(L),'\nM',''.join(M)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYyxCsIwFEX3fsVb5CUhFqxba/8gWbLWDoKNPmmSErr49TERanG5XM7h3uW9PoNvUrpPFiyLcuZtBa6fRex0PyDgKFxnfk1trQIbIhCQh3jzj4m5MgSyQId4ObVqoLHXJbDGTcxZmH@xRPJrvpRO4BElXr3JifUrkGeGF6B2oL5A70DzZFkjzzx9AA)

Comment: I've just copy-pasted this into TIO and taken the generated format from there. Turns out it's done in fewer bytes than you thought ;)

Comment: @Tfeld `r=4, l=8` works fine for me

Comment: The length is supposed to be the lowest common multiple. With r=4, l=8, that should be 8, but it appears your output is much longer (8*4?).

Comment: I forgot about that bit, thanks. I've added an updated version, but it is a lot longer.

Comment: That still does not give the LCM; eg for `15,25`, it gives `375`, but it should be `75`.

Comment: @O.O.Balance I think that's fixed it.

Comment: It seems it takes r,l as the interval between taps rather than the number of taps. My answer initially had the same issue. Also, could you please update the headline (byte-count) and TIO when you make changes?

Comment: @O.O.Balance I think I've fixed everything now. Please point out anything else I've missed though :)

Comment: That seems to print too few dashes, although I can't see why: https://tinyurl.com/ybpx5sfv Two golfing ideas: Could you use an infinite loop instead of range(r*l) since you're breaking the loop anyway? And might you replace `r==R.c … and L.c …` by something like `r*l==R.count(c)*L.count(c)`? Python is not my best language, but it could save you a few bytes.

Comment: I believe the last check can be replaced by `i%r+i%l+0**i<1`. Also, you can remove previous versions of code, as they will be preserved in your edit history of anyone wants to see them

Comment: @O.O.Balance I think it prints too few dashes because it's not taking into account the pause after the last beat. The `r*l` idea wouldn't work because it would display nothing if either `r` or `l` were 0. The infinite loop version seems to end up longer than the restricted one with the fix for the hyphens, but I'll keep trying to see if i cant get it lower.

Comment: @JoKing I'll remove the last versions on the next update then. I couldn't remember if SO kept the edit history because I don't spend much time on here now, and when I do it's on mobile.

Comment: I know I'm a bit late to point this out, but you don't need to account for `r==0` or `l==0`. The challenge specifies _positive_ integers.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>85</s> <s>80</s> 78 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Jo King.*

```perl6
{«'  'R L M»Z~'-'x($!=[lcm] @_),|(@_.=map:{' '~(0~' 'x$!/$_-1)x$_}),[~|] @_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/@tBqdQUF9SAFHwXfQ7uj6tR11Ss0VBRto3OSc2MVHOI1dWo0HOL1bHMTC6yq1RXU6zQM6oBUhYqivkq8rqFmhUp8raZOdF0NSHHt/7T8IgUNYx0FI00dBQ0THQVjKG0Kpc2htIWmQjUXp15xYqUCSEuahkq8pjUXJ5CvAaRr/wMA)

Returns a list of four lines.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 32 bytes

```
æl/Ḷ%Ɱµa/ṭ=0ị⁾. Z”-;ⱮZ“ RLM”żK€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wshz9hzu2qT7auO7Q1kT9hzvX2ho83N39qHGfnkLUo4a5utZAGSBjjkKQjy@Qf3SP96OmNZH///831TEBAA)

Takes input as a list `[L,R]`.

```
æl/       Get LCM of this list.
   Ḷ      Range [0..LCM-1]
    %Ɱ    Modulo by-each-right (implicitly the input, [L,R]):
           [[0%L ... (LCM-1)%L], [0%R ... (LCM-1)%R]]
µ         Take this pair of lists, and:
 a/ṭ      Append their pairwise AND to the pair.
    =0    Is zero? Now we have a result like:
              [[1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]
               [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
               [1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]]

ị⁾.       Convert this into dots and spaces.
Z”-;ⱮZ    Transpose, prepend a dash to each, transpose. Now we have
              ['---------------'
               '.  .  .  .  .  '
               '.    .    .    '
               '.  . ..  .. .  ']

“ RLM”ż       zip(' RLM', this)
       K€     Join each by spaces.
         Y    Join the whole thing by newlines.
```

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), 204 bytes

```
p(s){printf(s);}
g(a,b){a=b?g(b,a%b):a;}
h(r,l,m){for(;m;)p(m%r*(m--%l)?" ":".");}
f(r,l,m,i){m=r*l/g(r,l);p("  ");for(i=m;i-->0;)p("-");p("\nR ");h(m/r,m+1,m);p("\nL ");h(m/l,m+1,m);p("\nM ");h(m/r,m/l,m);}
```

Port of my Java [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169715/79343). Call with `f(number_of_right_hand_taps, number_of_left_hand_taps)`. Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##ZY9BawIxEIXP7q8IAwszOqmtChbD1j9QLz33kl3IGtjZhmhPwd@@TSqC4u3xvTfvMZ3uu26aAp4ohejHs8vKXKoeLbeUbNPue2zZ1i3tbOZHjDywUHI/EY0YCih1nKNoXQ@0BwU7eIHS4K5J9pSkifNh2RdAJiAolROlwDdivNYfr6UHNPy73@NX8Y8oy8iyeMtrV/x5w8MDPtyli5XHp/yIEutHJJWqmcMVqzWZahZ@zycEKNLhmtXqCW5YbZ9gPn/P6jL9AQ).

Comment: [200 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY/BCsIwEETP9itCoLBbN4pWUAzFH9CLZy9pIW2gqSXWU@m31w0iKJ52eDOzy1aqrqp57uGBYx9cN1hWeqrBUImjKcpTDSWZtMSj0VMDgVryONp7AO019uDTkIFXKm3xJIU8ypXkvn0HyfFWkEIwixVX@CJk7bqONmqnVFwhFds8bt01Bhvw60B@ueFDb3z@4PYHX77S0eK7M38gvHEdoBiThYUtiRx1suifwwOkjNJCTmL7B3ck9n@Q6wdW0/wC "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 53 bytes

```
j.b+NYc"  L R M "2++*\-J/*FQiFQKm*d+N*\ t/JdQsmeSd.TK
```

Definitely room to golf.  Will do so when I have time.
[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j.b%2BNYc%22%20%20L%20R%20M%20%222%2B%2B%2A%5C-J%2F%2AFQiFQKm%2Ad%2BN%2A%5C%20t%2FJdQsmeSd.TK&input=4%2C%207&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
j.b+NYc"  L R M "2++*\-J/*FQiFQKm*d+N*\ t/JdQsmeSd.TK
                       J/*FQiFQ                        Get the LCM.
                    *\-                                Take that many '-'s.
                               Km*d+N*\ t/dJQ          Fill in the taps.
                                             smeSd.TK  Get the metarhythm.
                  ++                                   Append them all.
      c"  L R M "2                                     Get the prefixes.
 .b+NY                                                 Prepend the prefixes.
j                                                      Join with newlines.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 254 bytes

---

**Golfed** [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFba8IwGH1ef8VHUJrQ2Dl1F@xSHwaDQctG@7CH2odSoxZK3JLIHrL8dpeKbsUFcuFcck7aWo1q1Rye96J@fBF6OqFw2nItG7GJYQ3sgCVtCYtNIzQo1sZy0c4lzZmKvrZNy3E@bOPxdz6U8ZjkgYPV0QyfuHNUxEiu91IgFL5Vq6zZbDXOryvqhz4JM/7RVjXHKETUzT@F48EnJLKnyzL26VyS0OR4aAlNGUKRYvm5xWjk8lOGsyIvg8Qt8d1s4e6cI0AkSKNTC4Beigom1B/5JBigpcjAZHYpEjCJ21IwqUWRPUSed/woRVmUHrihudJPleIKGAj@Bb8sGO@qA4rSwJTCBCz9A2YUppfA7SVwfwk8dEAXal2N9U7yqt7ic@JvE2hErxVxPTrL006oXcvDd9lojmGAnO9jr@eQzcGc5cW4tBSSPnJTuue/7nWnXQqzxj0thZ6MWAQk@p@VNML90aVAjrSed@YyXq2OFIkOPw)

```cs
(r,l)=>{int s=l>r?l:r,S=s;while(S%l>0|S%r>0)S+=s;string q(int a){return"".PadRight(S/a,'.').Replace(".",".".PadRight(a,' '));}string R=q(S/r),L=q(S/l),M="";s=S;while(S-->0)M=(R[S]+L[S]>64?".":" ")+M;return"  ".PadRight(s+2,'-')+$"\nR {R}\nL {L}\nM {M}";}
```

---

**Ungolfed**

```cs
( r, l ) => {
    int
        s = l > r ? l : r,
        S = s;

    while( S % l > 0 | S % r > 0 )
        S += s;

    string q( int a ) {
        return "".PadRight( S / a, '.' ).Replace( ".", ".".PadRight( a, ' ' ) );
    }

    string
        R = q( S / r ),
        L = q( S / l ),
        M = "";

    s = S;

    while( S-- > 0 )
        M = ( R[ S ] + L[ S ] > 64 ? "." : " " ) + M;

    return "  ".PadRight( s + 2, '-') + $"\nR {R}\nL {L}\nM {M}";
}
```

---

**Full code**

```cs
Func<Int32, Int32, String> f = ( r, l ) => {
    int
        s = l > r ? l : r,
        S = s;

    while( S % l > 0 | S % r > 0 )
        S += s;

    string q( int a ) {
        return "".PadRight( S / a, '.' ).Replace( ".", ".".PadRight( a, ' ' ) );
    }

    string
        R = q( S / r ),
        L = q( S / l ),
        M = "";

    s = S;

    while( S-- > 0 )
        M = ( R[ S ] + L[ S ] > 64 ? "." : " " ) + M;

    return "  ".PadRight( s + 2, '-') + $"\nR {R}\nL {L}\nM {M}";
};

Int32[][]
    testCases = new Int32[][] {
        new []{ 3, 2 },
        new []{ 4, 3 },
        new []{ 4, 5 },
        new []{ 4, 7 },
        new []{ 4, 8 },
    };

foreach( Int32[] testCase in testCases ) {
    Console.Write( $" Input: R: {testCase[0]}, L: {testCase[1]}\nOutput:\n{f(testCase[0], testCase[1])}" );
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

---

**Releases**

- **v1.0** - `254 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

**Notes**

- None

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>130</s> 126 bytes

```ruby
->*a{puts"  "+?-*s=a[0].lcm(a[1])
r,l=a.map!{|e|(?.+' '*(s/e-1))*e}
[?R,?L,?M].zip(a<<r.gsub(/ /){l[$`.size]}){|e|puts e*" "}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3RCoIwGIXvfYq/FbStOSuLArW9QN10OwatWCUYiJsXNffsVnr1cQ6H7zTt9d3fiz4@UO3r1lkEgBYiprbQcql4dXthLVeKRA2rCs1fup74znRY8MUc5hTbxMQrQqgJkRRnJo5MnBT/lDXWed7wh22vOIGE@ErOLtyWH6MC@Rv@Z2AoAhRC74z9pQIkyJStFQO5YemI7YjdiL0CFQ1rbvTtCb5zHQwqNPUuoAzukjqVDV3ovw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 52 bytes

```
≔θζＷ﹪ζη≧⁺θζζ↙≔⮌Ｅζ⟦¬﹪×ιθζ¬﹪×ιηζ⟧ζＦζ⊞ι⌈ι↓Ｅζ⭆ι§ .λ←↓RLM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY4xC8IwEIV3f8XR6Q6ii046CS6CkVLdxKFobAJpo01aS/98TGwVBJfj7t7d995F5vXF5Nr7tbWqqPDBoKfV5CmVFoDcXBttsGcgiYDn9@EqU4V0mOrGMhgf0lpVDmPHTStwuTHPaiduLixGciZaUVuBgRKBp71xH/5RlcKiCjCKtFD@iXIQz0SD5c3UEBwhbayMOs87VTYlKvrmeceIytvy4MKyiEO4XrttdRUdJjBLGGgi@mYfc/8gkmzHE1p5f1owmJ/9tNUv) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔θζＷ﹪ζη≧⁺θζ
```

Calculate the LCM of the inputs by taking the first multiple of `R` that's divisible by `L`.

```
ζ↙
```

Print the LCM, which automatically outputs the necessary row of `-`s. Then move to print the rhythm from right to left.

```
≔⮌Ｅζ⟦¬﹪×ιθζ¬﹪×ιηζ⟧ζ
```

Loop over the numbers from the LCM down to 0 and create an array of lists representing the beats of the right and left hands.

```
Ｆζ⊞ι⌈ι
```

Loop over the beats and add the metarhythm.

```
↓Ｅζ⭆ι§ .λ
```

Print the reversed beats downwards, but as this is an array they end up leftwards.

```
←↓RLM
```

Print the header.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 117 bytes

```python
a,b=input();n=a
while n%b:n+=a
for i in-1,1,2,3:print'_RLM '[i],''.join(' -'[i%2>>m*a%n|i/2>>m*b%n]for m in range(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BCoJAFEX38xWDMIzWs3AsCkO/oDZtQ2KUKV/kU8SooH@fXrY4cC8Xzu3fY9OR8c8G704mmXu5OggCb6HKkfrHGEY7yq3476SqjOZcL90gUSLFCSRgIM36AWnU5@P@IPUJS9B6ceuQQi1j7soURTuzij64nGKlqPw5WnbIwdLVhRRFfrII/hc@BSNWkDJrZsNsxRc)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 49 bytes

```
J/*FQiFQjC+c2" RLM    "ms@L" -"!M++0d*Fdm%Ld/LJQJ
```

Expects input in the form `[r,l]`. Uses `-` to display taps. Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%2F%2AFQiFQjC%2Bc2%22%20RLM%20%20%20%20%22ms%40L%22%20-%22%21M%2B%2B0d%2AFdm%25Ld%2FLJQJ&input=%5B2%2C3%5D&debug=0), or verify all test cases at once [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%2F%2AFQiFQjC%2Bc2%22%20RLM%20%20%20%20%22ms%40L%22%20-%22%21M%2B%2B0d%2AFdm%25Ld%2FLJQJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B3%2C2%5D%0A%5B4%2C3%5D%0A%5B4%2C5%5D%0A%5B4%2C7%5D%0A%5B4%2C8%5D&debug=0).

```
J/*FQiFQjC+c2" RLM    "ms@L" -"!M++0d*Fdm%Ld/LJQJ   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
 /*FQiFQ                                            Compute LCM: (a*b)/(GCD(a,b))
J                                                   Store in J
                                        m       J   Map d in [0-LCM) using:
                                            /LJQ      Get number of beats between taps for each hand
                                         %Ld          Take d mod each of the above
                                                    This gives a pair for each beat, with 0 indicating a tap
                       m                            Map d in the above using:
                                     *Fd              Multiply each pair (effecively an AND)
                                 ++0d                 Prepend 0 and the original pair
                               !M                     NOT each element
                        s@L" -"                       Map [false, true] to [' ', '-'], concatenate strings
                                                    This gives each column of the output
           c2" RLM    "                             [' RLM','    ']
          +                                         Prepend the above to the rest of the output
         C                                          Transpose
        j                                           Join on newlines, implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>161</s> <s>149</s> 146 bytes

```r
function(a,b){l=numbers::LCM(a,b)
d=c(0,' ')
cat('  ',strrep('-',l),'\nR ',d[(x<-l:1%%a>0)+1],'\nL ',d[(y<-l:1%%b>0)+1],'\nM ',d[(x&y)+1],sep='')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfa/s/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJszrHNq80Nym1qNjKysfZFyzGlWKbrGGgo66grsmVnFiioa6goK5TXFJUlFqgoa6rrpOjqaMekxcEFEyJ1qiw0c2xMlRVTbQz0NQ2jAXJ@EBkKqEySQgZX6getUqwSHFqga26umbt/1wNUx1DQ83/AA)

I definitely feel like there's room for improvement here, but I tried a few different approaches and this is the only one that stuck. <s>Getting rid of the internal function definition would make me quite happy, and I tried a bunch of restructures of the cat() to make it happen.</s> Nevermind, as soon as I posted I realised what I could do. Still definitely some efficiency savings to be found.

There are other LCM functions in libraries with shorter names, but TIO has numbers and I considered that more valuable at this point.

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 197 bytes

```cpp
int f(int a,int b){std::string t="  ",l="\nL ",r="\nR ",m="\nM ";int c=-1,o,p=0;for(;++p%a||p%b;);for(;o=++c<p;t+="-")l+=a*c%p&&++o?" ":".",r+=b*c%p&&++o?" ":".",m+=o-3?".":" ";std::cout<<t+l+r+m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY@/bsMgEIf3PMWJypHdw1Uat2ploHmBduncBWM7smT@iOApybO74ERdupjh9N2P706gnCuPSs0Pg1Hj1HbAB3sKvpP6Yx5MgD5PVdJUm@J8Cm1dx/vBHCEIAkDoKMiP@YzgE3xH0Am@gLA0pET5TC11Ysd663OG6DJ5ubisYcUtsQJRcccCClKSYkQhH1XmtltEeyBAavIUl6No/qcahS2rQ8Q6Rmx5nbJT4DzgiB41uy6/0HIweQHnDcTT5xXdF2zhvwng/NZ0ph3Z3Xuh1UrvdaX3ttJ7v3u@C5M3sGOb6/wL)

Comment: Suggest `++p%a+p%b` instead of `++p%a||p%b`