# Make some Alphabet Rain

Tags: code-golf, string, alphabet

## Alphabet Rain

### The Task:

The basic premise is to print out the input string and then repeat each character vertically, based on it's (0-indexed) position in the (case-insensitive) alphabet `A-Z`. `A` is at location 0 so is not repeated, `e` is at position 4 so is repeated 4 times, `P` is at position 15 so is repeated 15 times, `!` is not in `A-Z` so is repeated 0 times, etc.

For clarity, anything that falls outside of the range `B-Zb-z`, for example digits or special characters, will not be repeated, and thus will only appear on the first line.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest solution in each language is the winner.

### Input:

- Input will be in the standard printable ASCII character set, from 32   up to 126 `~`.
- The input string will be 1 character long or longer.
- There will not be any leading or trailing whitespace.
- You can take take input as a string (`"hello"`) or list of characters ( `["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]`)

### Examples:

Input of `aaaa` gives:

```
aaaa
```

Input of `abcda` gives:

```
abcda
 bcd
  cd
   d
```

Input of `Programming Puzzles & Code Golf!`, gives:

```
Programming Puzzles & Code Golf!
Progr mming Puzzles   Code Golf
Progr mming Puzzles   Code Golf
Progr mming Puzzles    ode Golf
Progr mming Puzzles    o e Golf
Progr mming Puzzl s    o   Golf
Progr mming Puzzl s    o   Gol
Pro r mmin  Puzzl s    o    ol
Pro r mmin  Puzzl s    o    ol
Pro r mm n  Puzzl s    o    ol
Pro r mm n  Puzzl s    o    ol
Pro r mm n  Puzzl s    o    ol
Pro r mm n  Puzz  s    o    o
Pro r    n  Puzz  s    o    o
Pro r       Puzz  s    o    o
Pr  r       Puzz  s
 r  r        uzz  s
 r  r        uzz  s
             uzz  s
             uzz
             uzz
              zz
              zz
              zz
              zz
              zz
```

Input of `~|[abc<0>cba]|~`, gives:

```
~|[abc<0>cba]|~
    bc   cb
     c   c
```

### Notes:

- standard loopholes apply
- output *can* be a list of strings, but:
- extraneous trailing newlines are not allowed (single `\n` on final line is acceptable)
- output *can* be a list of lists of characters, so long as it looks like it's raining characters
- no leading newline
- to our Nordic users who have a [few extra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_and_Norwegian_alphabet) letters in their "A-Z" alphabet, feel free to support them, but it's not part of the challenge

Comment: Is a single *leading* `\n` acceptable?

Comment: @Lynn, no leading newlines, the first line should be the input string/character list - I'll update the post!

Comment: FWIW, I think they look more like icicles than rain

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing sounds almost festive

Comment: :( Just Nordic?

Comment: Just cos I know the Danish alphabet goes `a-å` rather than `a-z`, so was just mean as a fun bonus if anyone wanted to tackle it :)

Answer (score 22):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), 113 bytes

```
00 C0 20 FD AE 20 9E AD 85 FB 20 A3 B6 A0 00 84 FC B1 22 99 6F C1 C9 41 90 14 
C9 5B B0 04 E9 40 B0 0E C9 C1 90 08 C9 DB B0 04 E9 C0 B0 02 A9 00 99 6F C0 C5 
FC 30 02 85 FC C8 C4 FB D0 D3 A9 00 99 6F C1 A0 C1 A9 6F 20 1E AB A9 0D 20 D2 
FF A6 FC D0 01 60 C6 FC A0 00 B9 6F C1 F0 E6 BE 6F C0 D0 07 A9 20 99 6F C1 D0 
05 CA 8A 99 6F C0 C8 D0 E7
```

[image: screenshot]

**[Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B%22controlPort2%22:%22joystick%22,%22primaryControlPort%22:2,%22keys%22:%7B%22SPACE%22:%22%22,%22RETURN%22:%22%22,%22F1%22:%22%22,%22F3%22:%22%22,%22F5%22:%22%22,%22F7%22:%22%22%7D,%22files%22:%7B%22rain.prg%22:%22data:;base64,AMAg/a4gnq2F+yCjtqAAhPyxIplvwclBkBTJW7AE6UCwDsnBkAjJ27AE6cCwAqkAmW/AxfwwAoX8yMT70NOpAJlvwaDBqW8gHqupDSDS/6b80AFgxvygALlvwfDmvm/A0AepIJlvwdAFyoqZb8DI0Oc=%22%7D,%22vice%22:%7B%22-autostart%22:%22rain.prg%22%7D%7D)**

**Usage:** `sys49152,"[string]"`, e.g. `sys49152,"Programming Puzzles & Code Golf!"`.

**Important:** If the program was loaded from disk (like in the online demo), issue a `new` command first! This is necessary because loading a machine program trashes some C64 BASIC pointers.

**Note:** The C64 is by default in a mode without lowercase letters -- in order to be able to enter a mixed-case string, switch to lowercase mode first by pressing `SHIFT`+`CBM`.

---

#### Explanation

Here's a commented disassembly listing:

```
         00 C0       .WORD $C000        ; load address
.C:c000  20 FD AE    JSR $AEFD          ; consume comma
.C:c003  20 9E AD    JSR $AD9E          ; evaluate expression
.C:c006  85 FB       STA $FB            ; store string length
.C:c008  20 A3 B6    JSR $B6A3          ; free string
.C:c00b  A0 00       LDY #$00           ; initialize counter
.C:c00d  84 FC       STY $FC            ; and number of "extra" lines
.C:c00f   .copyloop:                    
.C:c00f  B1 22       LDA ($22),Y        ; load next character
.C:c011  99 6F C1    STA .outbuf,Y      ; store to buffer
.C:c014  C9 41       CMP #$41           ; compare with 'a'
.C:c016  90 14       BCC .zerocount     ; smaller -> no repetition
.C:c018  C9 5B       CMP #$5B           ; compare with 'z'
.C:c01a  B0 04       BCS .checkupper    ; larger -> check for uppercase
.C:c01c  E9 40       SBC #$40           ; subtract 'a' ('a' - 1 and carry)
.C:c01e  B0 0E       BCS .cl_storecount ; and jump to store in repeat count
.C:c020   .checkupper:                  
.C:c020  C9 C1       CMP #$C1           ; compare with 'A'
.C:c022  90 08       BCC .zerocount     ; smaller -> no repetition
.C:c024  C9 DB       CMP #$DB           ; compare with 'Z'
.C:c026  B0 04       BCS .zerocount     ; larger -> no repetition
.C:c028  E9 C0       SBC #$C0           ; subtract 'A' ('A' - 1 and carry)
.C:c02a  B0 02       BCS .cl_storecount ; and jump to store in repeat count
.C:c02c   .zerocount:                   
.C:c02c  A9 00       LDA #$00           ; store 0 ...
.C:c02e   .cl_storecount:               
.C:c02e  99 6F C0    STA .repcount,Y    ; ... in repeat count
.C:c031  C5 FC       CMP $FC            ; compare with number of extra lines
.C:c033  30 02       BMI .cl_next       ; smaller -> go on with loop
.C:c035  85 FC       STA $FC            ; repeat count to number of extra lines
.C:c037   .cl_next:                     
.C:c037  C8          INY                ; next
.C:c038  C4 FB       CPY $FB            ; compare with string length
.C:c03a  D0 D3       BNE .copyloop      ; not yet reached? -> repeat
.C:c03c  A9 00       LDA #$00           ; terminate string in buffer
.C:c03e  99 6F C1    STA .outbuf,Y      ; with 0 byte
.C:c041   .outloop:                     
.C:c041  A0 C1       LDY #>.outbuf      ; output ...
.C:c043  A9 6F       LDA #<.outbuf      ; ...
.C:c045  20 1E AB    JSR $AB1E          ; ... string
.C:c048  A9 0D       LDA #$0D           ; and output ...
.C:c04a  20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2          ; ... newline
.C:c04d  A6 FC       LDX $FC            ; load extra line count
.C:c04f  D0 01       BNE .ol_step       ; not zero -> go on
.C:c051  60          RTS                ; WE ARE DONE HERE ;)
.C:c052   .ol_step:                     
.C:c052  C6 FC       DEC $FC            ; decrease extra line count
.C:c054  A0 00       LDY #$00           ; initialize counter
.C:c056   .eraseloop:                   
.C:c056  B9 6F C1    LDA .outbuf,Y      ; load next character from buffer
.C:c059  F0 E6       BEQ .outloop       ; 0 byte? -> end of string, output
.C:c05b  BE 6F C0    LDX .repcount,Y    ; load repeat count for this characer
.C:c05e  D0 07       BNE .el_step       ; not 0 yet? -> jump to decrement
.C:c060  A9 20       LDA #$20           ; load code for space
.C:c062  99 6F C1    STA .outbuf,Y      ; store in current string position
.C:c065  D0 05       BNE .el_next       ; and jump to next loop iteration
.C:c067   .el_step:                     
.C:c067  CA          DEX                ; decrease repeat count ...
.C:c068  8A          TXA                ; ... and ...
.C:c069  99 6F C0    STA .repcount,Y    ; ... store back
.C:c06c   .el_next:                     
.C:c06c  C8          INY                ; increase counter ...
.C:c06d  D0 E7       BNE .eraseloop     ; and jump back to loop

.C:c06f   .repcount:
.C:c06f              .RES $100          ; 256 bytes for repeat count
.C:c16f   .outbuf:
.C:c16f              .RES $100          ; 256 bytes as buffer for output
```

Comment: c64 machine code. I'm impressed.

Comment: @Dschoni thanks, but it's still simple code (and it's fun, for me!) -- you should have a look at the demo scene for really impressive C64 works ;)

Comment: If we're gonna keep getting these, we might want to set up links to a JavaScript C64 emulator so people can see them run.

Comment: @trlkly I have such a link in my submission, click on "Online demo" ;)

Answer (score 15):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
,εDlAsk×}ζ»,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f59xWlxzH4uzD02vPbTu0W@f//4Ci/PSixNzczLx0hYDSqqqc1GIFNQXn/JRUBff8nDRFAA)

**Explanation**

```
,             # print input
 ε      }     # apply to each char in input
  D           # duplicate
   l          # convert to lower case
    Ask       # get index of current char in the lower case alphabet
       ×      # repeat the char that many times
         ζ    # transpose with space as filler
          »,  # join on newlines and print
```

Comment: Need to get index of char in lowercase alphabet? just `Ask` for it

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, <s>12</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
.tm+*xGr0
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.tm%2B%2axGr0&input=%22Programming+Puzzles+%26+Code+Golf%21%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Programming+Puzzles+%26+Code+Golf%21%22%0A%22abcda%22%0A%22aaaa%22&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
.tm+*xGr0dddQ   Expanded program with autofilled input variable
  m      dddQ    For each character d in the input:
       r0d     get its lowercase variant
     xG        and return its 0-based index in the alphabet 
                   (-1 if not found, for special chars)
                (empty string for A/a and special characters)
    *     d    that many of the corresponding character
   +       d   and one more for good measure (because x is 0-indexed)
.t             Transpose it and fill blanks with spaces
```

12 bytes:

```
j.t*VmxGr0d
```

(with trailing newline)

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j.t%2aVmxGr0d%0A&input=%22Programming+Puzzles+%26+Code+Golf%21%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Programming+Puzzles+%26+Code+Golf%21%22%0A%22abcda%22%0A%22aaaa%22&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
j.t*VmxGr0d
QQ              Expanded program with autofilled input variable
Q               print the input verbatim
     m    dQ    For each character d in the input:
        r0      get its lowercase variant
      xG        and return its 0-based index in the alphabet 
                    (-1 if not found, for special chars)
   *V       Q   multiply the corresponding characters in (the second autofilled input)
                 by their alphabet indices we just calculated
                 (empty string for A/a and special characters)
 .t             Transpose it and fill blanks with spaces
j               Join the result on newlines
```

Comment: *output can be a list of lists of characters, so long as it looks like it's raining characters* - Hence you don't need `j`

Comment: Ah, you're right! I was keeping it because the 12-byte version was printing one line verbatim and I couldn't mix the formats like that, and I forgot I could remove that now that everything is in the transpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 83 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,k=65:[*{*s}-{' '}]and[s]+f([[' ',c][91>ord(c.upper())>k]for c in s],k+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBC4IwGIDhc/2Kr0vb1ASJggSF8tDV@1iwprPl3GSrQ4r9dbPj@8Dbf14Pa/bzLDPNu3vFwUdtdjykNBgDP@1GBGhi3FTUs1BiSpeOBKOnJLeuwiJ@933tMCF5y6R1IEAZ8Cxqw4TMf9B/kFgr/8KodLZxvOuUaaB8D4OuPWyhsFUNV6vlhrLbOH3P/HIvBCIkXa96p8wyovhplcGakPkH) Takes a list of characters. Returns a list of lists of characters.

### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 90 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,k=65:s.strip()and s+'\n'+f(''.join([' ',c][91>ord(c.upper())>k]for c in s),k+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvBCoIwGADgV/m7tA2HYFBQoFAeuno3g7k5W@q/sekho1599d0/95ofFncx6nwUU6sEBD7kh/0ppGH2xlEmUEFIyA1Joikh6dMapDUBwmVTH7PCekVlujjXecpYMTTaepBgEALjQ5Kx6LzBGf658rb3YpoM9lAt6zp2AbZQWtXB1Y56Uzf39@d7Fpe2lITFHw) Takes a string. Returns a string.

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, <s>115</s> 89 bytes

It takes as `input` a **list of characters**  `[{"a", "b", "c", "d", "a"}]` and outputs **a list of lists of characters**

```
Thread[PadRight[Table[#,Max@Position[Alphabet[]/."a"->#,#|ToLowerCase@#]]&/@#]/. 0->" "]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxCsMgFEDRXxGFTCb2BxosXVuQ4iYOzygqJLGYBy20/XbrcO52N8AUNsC8QIvnplMN4I0C/8gxodHg1mAYv8NbqnJkzGU3l/WZwAU0VkwU6Dgzzr663Mor1CscQTJrB9ErJnIaZ0qoHZqqeUcio/n0hVPXLZ3vgP5sa38)

*-26 bytes from Misha Lavrov*

*-5 bytes from user202729*

but if you want to see the output as it is in the test case, try this (128 bytes) code
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY7BCsIwEAV/JW6gKFTrB2iJ9OBFIWhvMYfVbpNA20gaUcR/j7m@gZk3YrQ0YnQPTGafrjG4yVxc3w@kAHY1LyqxbG0g7ITE7uKMjarFe8a8PONHSD@76PykDsPT4p2i0tUGENY1L/mv9Sf/ptDgTIJrnWWNxYCPSGHOQ7Vh23UNDFYl3CbQRZK5H5kwCmTwJuA45j9Mvr7fgWZWsMZ3xI5@6BegU/oD)

Comment: For future readers: The part "this answer only works on Mathematica..." is a bit misleading, the problem is Mathematica only support Unicode character in notebook (REPL) mode. In [script mode](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html), it only understand ASCII and special characters which have been converted to ASCII (e.g., `∞` (3 bytes) -> `\[Infinity]` (11 bytes)).

Comment: @user202729 ok,I'll edit and address people to read your comment.thanks

Comment: Golf suggestion for Mathematica (script mode): `\[Infinity]` (11 bytes) can be replaced by `Infinity` (8 bytes) or `\:221e` (6 bytes). The last one is the default representation of special characters without names. (although it is not the main part)

Comment: We can avoid `Infinity` entirely. The problematic part is `If[(d=Min@Position[Alphabet[],If[UpperCaseQ@#,ToLowerCase@#,#]])==∞,1,d]` and we can change this to `Max@Position[Alphabet[]/."a"->#,#|ToLowerCase@#]`. (Searching in the list `{#,b,c,d,...,y,z}`, we're guaranteed to find `#` at least once.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov very nice. fixed it!

Answer (score 6):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>27</s> 22 bytes

*5 bytes saved thanks to @Adám*

```apl
⍉∘↑⊢⍴¨⍨1⌈27|⎕A⍳819⌶⍨∘1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHvZ2POmY8apv4qGvRo94th1Y86l1h@Kinw8i85lHfVMdHvZstDC0f9WwDCgPVGQI1KagHFOWnFyXm5mbmpSsElFZV5aQWK6gpOOenpCq45@ekKaoDAA)

**How?**

`⍴¨⍨` - shape each char to length of

`1⌈` - at least one or

`⎕A⍳819⌶⍨∘1` - index of the char uppercased in alphabet

`27|` - modulo 27

`↑` - flatten to a matrix

`⍉` - and transpose

Comment: 22 bytes: [`⍉∘↑⊢⍴¨⍨1⌈27|⎕A⍳819⌶⍨∘1`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHvZ2POmY8apv4qGvRo94th1Y86l1h@Kinw8i85lHfVMdHvZstDC0f9WwDCgPVGQI1KagHFOWnFyXm5mbmpSsElFZV5aQWK6gpOOenpCq45@ekKaoDAA)

Comment: @Adám thanks!  updated

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
θ↙↓Ｅ⮌θ×ι⌕α↥ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVAAr/9jaGFyY29hbP//zrjihpnihpPvvKXirozOuMOXzrnijJXOseKGpc65//9bJ1Byb2dyYW1taW5nIFB1enpsZXMgJiBDb2RlIEdvbGYnXf8tYQ)

-3 thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil).

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>111</s> <s>106</s> <s>99</s> <s>98</s> <s>97</s> <s>87</s> 93 bytes

```python
s=input()
i=65
while s.strip():print s;s=''.join([' ',c][91>ord(c.upper())>i]for c in s);i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxDoIwEADQna84F9tGQ4KJJkrK4uDKThgMFDgDveaujZGfr@@FX1zIX3IWiz6kqE2B9nYtvguuDqSUyBi0eQRGH0FqsUqVH0KvOwXqPPTdvWqIRz2UKQTH2pgG@4kYBkAPYmo82Spn1TLN/N429DO0ad9XJ3CEJ40OXrROB/UH)

Comment: `while`can be replaced with `exec` to save few bytes, `i`can start with 65 to save more one [to reach 87 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcG7DoIwFADQna@4MthWDQkkkpjSycGVnTCYUvAa6G36SBQ/vp7jvvFFtsk5KLQuRS4KVO21MB@jS@fRRggyKMaqN6HlAwN20eOAHfmJ6yo5ZzwXorvV40weNKCFICSeVS3LU9PmzHpPi39uG9oF@rTvqwlwhDtNBh60zocf@wM)

Comment: The OP says _extraneous trailing newlines are not allowed_, but your code prints several of them when the input doesn’t contain `z` or `Z`.

Comment: @Lynn Fixed, I forgot to double-check the `exec`change...

Answer (score 5):

## Python, <s>105</s> 103 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @TFeld*

```python
lambda s:'\n'.join(''.join((' '+l)[i<1or 91>ord(l.upper())>i+64]for l in s)for i in range(26)).rstrip()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcmxCsIwEIDhVzkXc0ehUJWCol0cXLtbh0iTepIm4dIO9uWjBaf/gz9@plfw@2wvXXZ6fPYa0kl1XpXvwB7Vv6hAFY7ufK6CwLFqgvToyjlGI0jUcFEfHva3HLCHRCt5pWg/GNzVRKWkSTgi5SjsJ7SoWgmD6HFkP0A7L4szCbZwDb2BW3B2o4jyFw)

Comment: [103 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcmxCsIwEIDhVzkXc0ehUJWCol0cXLtbh0iTepIm4dIO9uWjBaf/gz9@plfw@2wvXXZ6fPYa0kl1XpXvwB7Vv6hAFY7ufK6CwLFqgvToyjlGI0jUcFEfHva3HLCHRCt5pWg/GNzVRKWkSTgi5SjsJ7SoWgmD6HFkP0A7L4szCbZwDb2BW3B2o4jyFw)

Comment: @TFeld nice catch, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 162 bytes

```cs
s=>{string A="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",r=s;for(int i=-1;++i<s.Max(A.IndexOf);)r+='\n'+string.Concat(s.Select(c=>A.IndexOf(char.ToLower(c))>i?c:' '));return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBPS8NAEMXPyacYczAb0i54Nd1IKShCi4UKPaiHdbNJV5NdO7PpX/rZYySip8fw3vvBG0Vj5VB3LRlbwepIXjd8buw2C1UtiWAZnsOAvPRGwc6ZAhbSWGDksS@8vIHEipIw6EPBb/u@tWoy@CMYNIcSREciPw83TEUk31Why2pjPj7rxrqvLZJvd/vD8RSNUFBWOmTGejBifJOlqZkQX8gDm/JHW@jDU5lkCaYifrVxOkD5zFklPSO@0rVWnimR/6WZ2kjkz27u9hqZSpLc3KnbGOIkyVD7Fi1gdumy/xk9jVyt@RqN1/1HNCtZtERXoWyanw3L9nSqNcE1zFyh4cHV5VXU48LgEl66bw)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and nice first answer. You can shorten your code by using a few tricks. Here is a more _golfed_ version of your code: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBfS8MwFMWf209x7YNN6Bbw1S6VMVCEDQcTfFAfYpp20TRxuen@ss9eqxUEn@69nN85cK7EsXRedS1qW8PqgEE1bK7tJo@lEYiwjE9xhEEELWHrdAkLoS0QDL43PL@C8DXSOOqh6Nd921o5GfQRDLOACniHvDgNN0x5It5kqap6rd8/TGPd58ZjaLe7/eGYjDzHXNsAmo@v8t1aG0WyTE@QLcSeSF5M2b0t1f6hIpJS6jOevtg0G7LZzFkpAkG2UkbJ8I9nj271wxHar3O3U55QWugbeZ1CSmnuVWi9BZ@fu/yvVB@Kzij25HVQ/X8UqUiy9K72omm@Gy3b49EohEuYuVLBnTPVRdLHxdE5Pndf "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online").

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I assumed my code had to be executable by itself, so I built it upon that assumption! Thanks for the comment and the mentoring.

Comment: If you want to find some more tricks on how to golf in C#, take a look at [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c) post, or take a look at existing C# answers. Happy golfing!

Comment: Nice answer. Keep going :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! Great first answer, especially now that it's golfed. +1 from me. Btw, it's currently 180 bytes, not 162. The required import `using System.Linq;` is unfortunately mandatory to add to the byte-count (or you should change `Max` to `System.Linq.Max` and `Select` to `System.Linq.Max`, which would be higher than simply `using System.Linq;` once.) Again welcome, and enjoy your stay. Oh, and I see @IanH. already mentioned Tips for Golfing in C#. [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5285/52210) might also be interesting to read through.

Answer (score 5):

## Bash, <s>78</s>, <s>76</s> 71 bytes

```
for c in {B..a};{ [[ -n ${1// } ]]&&echo "$1";set "${1//[!$c-Z${c,}-z]/ }";}
```

Depending on collation (default LC_ALL) can save some more bytes

```
for c in {b..z} _;{ [[ -n ${1// } ]]&&echo "$1";set "${1//[!$c-Z]/ }";}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##Fcq9DoMgFIbhW/kkhE2NM2OHrs4lpFGKP4lyErALhGs/tdubPO88pY15oQiHPaDMXZcr3rrAGLQBsgx9jwprlfJuIwg5CJ38dcefTCNd@7L3InRl5jHSGqfz3MOK8Zvz4RMUHvTxeNKxND8)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 43 bytes

**41 bytes code + 2 for `-nl`.**

```perl
$c=A;print,s/$c|[^a-z]/ /gi,$c++while/\S/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l2dbRuqAoM69Ep1hfJbkmOi5RtypWX0E/PVNHJVlbuzwjMydVPyZY////xKTklNRErkQg4Aooyk8vSszNzcxLVwgorarKSS1WUFNwzk9JVXDPz0n7l19QkpmfV/xfNy8HAA)

Comment: loop for [_0-9] characters, maybe `s/["-$c]/ /gi` and `-l` not needed

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Ahh, yes, I was a little too quick on the test cases. They should be added to the OP! :) Thanks! +4 :(

Comment: my suggestion doesn't work for any characters between 32 and 126 (non alpha greater than Z)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Can't find a shorter way that meets all requirements... I'll keep playing...

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>87</s> <s>78</s> 76 bytes

*-9 bytes thanks to [@RickHitchcock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42260/rick-hitchcock).*
*-2 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil).*

```js
f=(s,i=10)=>s.trim()&&s+`
`+f(s.replace(/./g,c=>parseInt(c,36)>i?c:" "),i+1)
```

Takes input as a string and returns with one trailing newline.

### Test Cases

```js
f=(s,i=10)=>s.trim()&&s+`
`+f(s.replace(/./g,c=>parseInt(c,36)>i?c:" "),i+1)

;["hello", "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf!", "~|[abc<0>cba]|~", "abcdefg0123456789"]
.forEach(s=>console.log(f(s)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: 76 bytes (one trailing new line):  `f=(s,i=10)=>s.trim()&&s+'newline'+f(s.replace(/./g,c=>parseInt(c,36)-i?c:" "),i+1)`

Comment: @RickHitchcock That seems to infinite loop for an input string containing numbers: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLDoMgEADQvacwLMxMRNRq7S/YdW8hHcHQWDGM6fXpex/zM0zR70e1hdmm5DSw9LptUI@sjui/gEXB5ZRNpQNW0e6rIQu1qhdJetxNZPvaDiDZDVj5J91FLlD6ssX0yChsHFar1rBA7kCYN83WLU176vrzcLneBOaY/g). The idea of step-by-step changes to `s` is really nice, though.

Comment: Ahh, good point.  That can be fixed at the cost of 2 bytes: `parseInt(c,36)-i>0`

Comment: @RickHitchcock Can you not use `parseInt(c,36)>i` instead to save 2 bytes?

Comment: @Neil, duh.  Justin:  What Neil said.  : )

Comment: @RickHitchcock Updated, thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>125</s> 123 bytes

*[Outgolfed by plannapus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144905/67312)*

```r
for(i in 1:max(p<-pmax(1,match(tolower(S<-el(strsplit(scan(,""),''))),letters),na.rm=T)))cat(ifelse(p<i," ",S),'\n',sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxLCsMwDAWvEryxDEoh25KcIl12o7gKMfiHLGh7etddPRhmnvQYDiH5QmK9yqu5fhaBMIU8LfdEH6jrXP@7YCL1F2iJ5c0C@zpzhKbSagwKzVMGNMahtc45jKzK0hxmuknaHoN5Uggnx8bjNKCdLO5Df2aLjes2um7o8C8y/Qc)

Prints to stdout with a single trailing newline and reads from `stdin()`.

Let's break it down:

```r
S <- el(strsplit(scan,""))            # split the string to characters

m <- match(tolower(S),letters)        # 1-based index in letters (lowercase a-z)
p <- pmax(1,m,na.rm=T)                # parallel max, replaces NA (non-alphabet) or 0 with 1
for(i in 1:max(p)){                   # iterate
 cat(                                 # print
  ifelse(p<1,' ',S),                  # the corresponding letter in S if p>=1, space otherwise
  '\n',sep='')                        # newline, and no spaces between chars
}
```

### Alternate answer, 106 bytes

```r
function(S)for(i in 1:max(p<-pmax(1,match(tolower(S),letters),na.rm=T)))cat(ifelse(p<i,' ',S),'\n',sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYu7DsIwDAB3viKbbSlF6opaJv4ARpZQHDVSXnKMAKn/Hsp0w91Jj@EhTr6YWNfybHTwZhq6f@VFQ8l4JV8EgwnZjKfkPlinof452uR0WVFLLG@WPbSRVVka2eyOkuYbES1OMXiOjfcxWDBg9xDuGWzjOgNQ98gRm0qrMSiCm7bLdnZgd0fUfw)

Function; prints to stdout but it's basically my response above ported to accept a list of characters rather than splitting the string, so I feel like it's "cheating." Plus, plannapus' approach with regex is quite neat!

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, <s>74</s> 66 bytes

```matlab
@(s)char(arrayfun(@(c){repmat(c,1,prod(find(upper(c)==65:90)))},s))'
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##DclLCsIwEADQq8SNmYEQdKGgECh04bZXGPKphebDpBGsePbo275sN3r5HozWug9Q0T6JgZjpHVqCASx@2JdIG1h1VoWzg7AkB60Uz/815nq5306I@FUVUfYAcuI8M8W4pFlMbd9XX8VRjNl58chrOEjsPw)

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>118</s> 114 bytes

```
function(a)while(grepl("[^ ]",a)){F=F+1;cat(a,"\n");for(j in c("[^a-zA-Z]",letters[F],LETTERS[F]))a=gsub(j," ",a)}
```

Thanks to @Giuseppe for those 4 bytes off

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBC4IwGMbxe59i7RAbKdTZDCK0SwcpT5nB69xMmVtMJTDzqy@l2/@BH4@xwreiU6wttSJA389SclIY/pIEJw@UYgco/YR@uN56DFoCDr4rTD2hDalQqRCbHbj9wb1NWPK25aZJwtQ5B3EcXK5TUgp@0XQZqRyM5sOvFQRHRhcG6rpUBYq6vpe8QSt01DlHJy3FEtPFpCBjOfxzHJJp7TZ7lkE6jJjaHw)

Short explanation:

```r
function(a)
    while(grepl("[^ ]",a)){ #As long as the string is not just spaces.
        F=F+1 #Increment letter counter (F is FALSE, hence 0 by default)
        cat(a,"\n") #Print string
        for(j in c("[^a-zA-Z]",letters[F],LETTERS[F])) #Get rid of non-letters, and the current letter in lower and upper case
             a=gsub(j," ",a)
    }
```

Comment: ohhh, wait, potential issue: if `a` is all spaces, this won't print out anything...but you can change the `while` condition to `grepl()|!F` which is still a byte shorter than your original answer.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>69 78 77</s> 85+1 bytes

```php
for($c=A;!$c[1]&&~trim($s=&$argn);$s=eregi_replace("[^".++$c."-Z]"," ",$s))echo"$s
";
```

requires PHP<7. Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/97c87c85e9a7b186f01e5d1bb08825638b996927).

Comment: @Shaggy thanks for pointing out. It´s complete now.

Comment: +1 for `$c=A;!$c[1];$c++`. Nice one! Sadly `extraneous trailing newlines are not allowed (single \n on final line is acceptable)`. So it fails for all strings not containing `z`.

Comment: @Christoph fixed

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

First chance to play with Japt's new string padding methods so there might still be room for improvement.

```
y_ùZInZu c
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=eV/5WkluWnUgYw==&input=IlByb2dyYW1taW5nIFB1enpsZXMgJiBDb2RlIEdvbGYhIg==)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of string `U`.

```
y_
```

Pass each column of `U` through a function, where `Z` is the current element (or letter, in this case).

```
InZu c
```

Convert `Z` to uppercase (`u`), get its charcode (`c`) and subtract (`u`) 64 (`I`).

```
ùZ
```

Pad the start of `Z` with itself until it reaches that length.

---

### Alternative

```
y_ùZ9aZn36
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=eV/5WjlhWm4zNg==&input=IlByb2dyYW1taW5nIFB1enpsZXMgJiBDb2RlIEdvbGYhIg==)

Comment: But couldn't you change `ùZ` to `p` to save a b...never mind, that's really clever...

Comment: @ETHproductions: I made a few attempts with `p` (there *might* be 1 in the edit history) but `ù` won out in the end.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>137</s> <s>136</s> <s>127</s> 119 bytes

```hs
import Data.Char
p c=last$0:[k|k<-[0..25],k+65==ord(toUpper c)]
f s=[[last$c:[' '|i>p c]|c<-s]|i<-[0..maximum$map p s]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYy9CsIwGABn@xSfUqyihiLoUIyLgouCIE4hyEd/bGjShCQFkeKr16qr6x13Jboql7LrhDLaetijR7Ir0QYGUirR@TBOWNVWmwWLCVmu@LyarVeUaptNvL4ak1tIpzwowFHGvkGasAiiVmz7BW/TzcLxVvx6hQ@hGhUqNGDAcd4pFDXNdDDo0ekGpvEXb481hFDAZ0NI9Ir4Xz06W323qJSo73Bunk@ZOxjDTmc5HLQshqPuDQ)

Pretty long but I can't think of any way to shorten it further. <s>I feel like there must be some way shorter than the if-then syntax but I don't see it.</s>

EDIT: Thanks @streetster for helping me shave off one byte! I didn't use `toUpper` at first because of the cost of importing `Data.Char` but I forgot that it also provides `ord` which is much shorter than `fromEnum`

EDIT 2: Thanks to @Laikoni for shaving off another 6 bytes and identifying a bug which I have now fixed. I used 26 instead of 25 because I forgot that Haskell arrays are inclusive. Then I noticed I could use `last` instead of `head` which would allow me to use `0:` rather than `++[0]`.

EDIT 3: Thanks again Laikoni for those 8 bytes. I had actually forgotten about that space. For some reason Sublime Text flips out without it and I  forgot to remove it. I wasn't aware that lists of lines were allowed, I should've read the rules more carefully.

Comment: Can you lowercase the input to avoid having to check A-Z as well as a-z and then mod'ing?

Comment: @streetster In haskell the toLower and toUpper functions require importing Data.Char which costs more chars than it saves. [TIO](https://tio.run/##VY69asMwFEbn@ilug6kaEos8gNUlhSwdAh2Fhot9HV@sPySZFmP66q47lrN@nO@MmCeydtvYxZAKvGNBeR0xVRE6NRL2tWZYX/k8Hdtm4agvUppaCxRSikWY86RUCR/hixJ05nTSF1MNkNXsLXvKWvMA/LbLoIzkQeyQzQTd2rVNNiu3zZ/S4Te72dUOI0TIxmwO2as@VE9xLp8lQQ0DHO4pPBI6x/4B93lZLGV4gWvoCW7BDs@Hf3O9v@2VP8Jsvw)

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [tips for golfing in Haskell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell). E.g. `if i>p c then ' ' else c` can be shortened to `last$c:[' '|i>p c]`.

Comment: Two more things: There is an unnecessary space in `[k |`  and returning a list of lines is allowed, so you don't need the `unlines`. Finally, you might be interested in our [Haskell chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66515/of-monads-and-men).

Answer (score 3):

## Excel VBA, 110 Bytes

Anonymous VBE Immediate Window Function that takes input as expected type `Variant\String` from range `[A1]` and uses it to make it rain the alphabet in the VBE immediate window.

```vb
?[A1]:For i=1To 26:For j=1To[Len(A1)]:c=Mid([A1],j,1):d=Asc(UCase(c)):?IIf((d>64+i)*(d<91),c," ");:Next:?:Next
```

#### Sample I/O

```vb
[A1]="qwertyuiop[]ASDFGHJKL:'zxcvbnm,./"
?[A1]:For i=1To 26:For j=1To[Len(A1)]:c=Mid([A1],j,1):d=Asc(UCase(c)):?IIf((d>64+i)*(d<91),c," ");:Next:?:Next
qwertyuiop[]ASDFGHJKL:'zxcvbnm,./
qwertyuiop   SDFGHJKL  zxcvbnm   
qwertyuiop   SDFGHJKL  zxcv nm   
qwertyuiop   SDFGHJKL  zx v nm   
qwertyuiop   S FGHJKL  zx v nm   
qw rtyuiop   S FGHJKL  zx v nm   
qw rtyuiop   S  GHJKL  zx v nm   
qw rtyuiop   S   HJKL  zx v nm   
qw rtyuiop   S    JKL  zx v nm   
qw rtyu op   S    JKL  zx v nm   
qw rtyu op   S     KL  zx v nm   
qw rtyu op   S      L  zx v nm   
qw rtyu op   S         zx v nm   
qw rtyu op   S         zx v n    
qw rtyu op   S         zx v      
qw rtyu  p   S         zx v      
qw rtyu      S         zx v      
 w rtyu      S         zx v      
 w  tyu      S         zx v      
 w  tyu                zx v      
 w   yu                zx v      
 w   y                 zx v      
 w   y                 zx        
     y                 zx        
     y                 z         
                       z
```

Comment: Brutal!!! It seams you can also make `?A1:...`

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ, unfortunately, as the `[]` indicates that the contained string should be evaluated to an object in/on/as a workbook, the `[A1]` call may not reduced to `A1` - as this will not take and print the initial input from the range `[A1]`; rather this will just leave an empty line and all subsequent lines will be printed

Comment: Ups, you're right... Didn't notice this!

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + sed, 37

```bash
sed -rne"/^ *$/q;p;s/\W|"{a..z}/\ /gi
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RUG3KC9VST9OQUtFv9C6wLpYPya8Rqk6UU@vqlY/RkE/PfP//4Ci/PSixNzczLx0hYDSqqqc1GIFNQXn/JRUBff8nDRFrsSk5JREAA).

Comment: it looks like it's repeating characters in the alphabet 1-too-many times

Comment: @streetster I think its fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>70</s> <s>67</s> 74 bytes

```
f=->s{puts s;(?b..?z).each{|c|s.gsub! /[^#{c}-z]/i,' ';puts s if s=~/\S/}}
```

Thanks to [@TuukkaX](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41754/tuukkax) for pointing out some parens could be dropped (-3 bytes)

Unfortunately I then had to add 7 bytes because original version failed to handle "z".

Calling it:

```
f.call('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!')
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!
The quick brown fox jumps over the l zy dog
The quick  rown fox jumps over the l zy dog
The qui k  rown fox jumps over the l zy dog
The qui k  rown fox jumps over the l zy  og
Th  qui k  rown fox jumps ov r th  l zy  og
Th  qui k  rown  ox jumps ov r th  l zy  og
Th  qui k  rown  ox jumps ov r th  l zy  o
T   qui k  rown  ox jumps ov r t   l zy  o
T   qu  k  rown  ox jumps ov r t   l zy  o
T   qu  k  rown  ox  umps ov r t   l zy  o
T   qu     rown  ox  umps ov r t   l zy  o
T   qu     rown  ox  umps ov r t     zy  o
T   qu     rown  ox  u ps ov r t     zy  o
T   qu     row   ox  u ps ov r t     zy  o
T   qu     r w    x  u ps  v r t     zy
T   qu     r w    x  u  s  v r t     zy
T    u     r w    x  u  s  v r t     zy
T    u       w    x  u  s  v   t     zy
T    u       w    x  u     v   t     zy
     u       w    x  u     v         zy
             w    x        v         zy
             w    x                  zy
                  x                  zy
                                     zy
                                     z
```

Comment: The parentheses at the lambda definition can be removed. +1.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 189 bytes

```c
#define F for(q=c,p=s;*p;++p,++q)
char*p,*q,s[99],c[99];main(h){gets(s);F{*q=*p>64&&*p<91?*p-65:*p>96&&*p<123?*p-97:0;h=h>*q?h:*q;}for(puts(s);h--;){F{putchar(*q?--*q,*p:32);}putchar(10);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BioMwFEX38xUZCmKeCWg7tcTUdlFwtt2XWUgajVD1xYybit/uxA7dXLiHyz2K10oty@auq6bTpCBVP4Q2VwxzJwFlFCGLIks/lCkHQAaWuZsQP0ytKduy6UJDp1r/utBRWUxgc8BT@hUEgEeRnAF5us88EukLJdvdysQhi6XJzQns2WRg5byKcfy/MZxLOhWT76s39CPOvRow222pnN88iX2Zl@U69PVQtm3T1eQ6Pp8P7UhALv1dk@/@UX3@AQ)

Comment: Try `puts("");` instead of `putchar(10)`

Comment: [178 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY3LDoIwFET3fkXVxNBLm/jElIouTHDr3rggtVASgVsqG4zfjlQ3k8nJZI7ihVLDMH/ovKw1SUnetIFNFMPESUAZhsjC0NKJMlkLyMAydxPizpRPWWVlHRj6LvTLBY7KFGwCeIy2C8CDWJ0AebSLRyIiT1brjUdiHy@ZScwR7MnEYKWXYve/MJzLX5/NKE3JWL06GKecj3bAeLOm8jMM17Yp2qyqyrog167vn9qRBTk3D00uzTOffgE "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 98 bytes

```hs
p c=sum[length[a..c]|a:e<-["B[","b{"],[c]<e]
f s=[[last$c:[' '|i>p c]|c<-s]|i<-[0..maximum$p<$>s]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY2xDoIwFABn@YpnQ2SBxpkAgw6uJI7NG2op0NgWQtvEYOOvI36A8@XuRu6eUuttm0HULhimpR38yDilAiMvZVUwcmEkJ483wZwJrCQmPbiaMc2dT0XJMsiiavYARlEVDqPapTOlhr@UCSadq7RxiJvhytbdlBzm4O9@AQrBamWlgxR6IO0yDQs3RtkB2rCuegcnuE6dhNuk@yP5I/7@lGafDLcv)

Example usage: `f "[Abc]"` yields a list of lines: `["[Abc]","  bc ","   c "]`. Use `putStr.unlines.f $ "[Abc]"` for pretty-printed output:

```
[Abc]
  bc
   c
```

<s>Partly inspired by</s> Now directly based on [user1472751's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144911/56433).

---

#### Previous approach (<s>100</s> 99 bytes)

```hs
f s=[h|i<-[0..26],h<-[[(c:concat[c<$[a..c]|[a,e]<-["B[","b{"],c<e]++cycle" ")!!i|c<-s]],any(>' ')h]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc69CsIwFIbh3as4DcUoxiAODlIddHAtOIYzxGPaBtNE@jO0Fm899gbcPnj44K10@zLOxVhAe1LVZLOt2km5P6Co5qlWdKTgSXeKslRpKQknpYXBGdlFMcEeH4aCMoObDQ3kDAO2ThI7UbZtEYX2w@rMga8rjLW2Hk7wDAsAePfdvWtAQu@d9aaFFApg@kHsv@ZNKBtd19aXkPfj6GZYwjU8DdyCK5L/VzUnSMm/HOMP)

Answer (score 2):

## Oracle SQL, 186 Bytes

Assumes the string will be in a table `t` in column `v`:

```
WITH a(s,l)AS(SELECT v,64 FROM t UNION ALL SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(s,'[^'||CHR(l+1)||'-Z]',' ',1,0,'i'),l+1 FROM a WHERE l<90)SELECT LISTAGG(RTRIM(s),CHR(10))WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY l)FROM a
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fdd1d/15)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( v ) AS
SELECT '~|[abc<0>cba]|~' FROM DUAL
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH a(s,l)AS(
  SELECT v,64 FROM t
UNION ALL
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(s,'[^'||CHR(l+1)||'-Z]',' ',1,0,'i'),l+1
  FROM a
  WHERE l<90
)
SELECT LISTAGG(RTRIM(s),CHR(10))WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY l)
FROM a
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fdd1d/15/0)**:

```
|      LISTAGG(RTRIM(S),CHR(10))WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYL) |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
| ~|[abc<0>cba]|~                                     |
|    abc   cba                                        |
|     bc   cb                                         |
|      c   c                                          |
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>122</s> 127 bytes

```powershell
param($a)$a;(1..25|%{$i=$_;(-join([char[]]$a|%{(' ',$_)[$_-match'[a-z]'-and[math]::Max(0,($_-bor32)-96-$i)]})).TrimEnd()})-ne''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBC4IwFMDxr9LhxXuDJmYUpNWtY7duY8hzClvolBUUpX715fX/@w/9uwlP27RtjAMH7ghYABe0TZJsP65/4M5QFiQfvfOkjOWgtAZehHCFGyiFglJ2/DIWFcuvRsm@VkuwOs9v/KF0Q8tR9WGXCXk8SHBCT0Ik9@C6q69JTEL6BjHGiPOouDKn9GIq1uOMfw)

Short thanks to how PowerShell can dynamically cast between `[char]` and `[int]`, but long because of removing extraneous whitespace and the calculation of whether to output a space or the character.

*Bugfix thanks to beatcracker.*

Comment: Unfortunately, this fails on `~|[abc<0>cba]|~` test case. Try this: `param($a)$a;(1..25|%{$i=$_;(-join([char[]]$a|%{(' ',$_)[$_-match'[a-z]'-and[math]::Max(0,($_-bor32)-96-$i)]})).TrimEnd()})-ne''`

Comment: @beatcracker Good catch. That's a clever way of handling the comparison. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
ØaḊiÐ€Œl‘⁸ẋ"z⁶Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUoAtf9qZWxsef//w5hh4biKacOQ4oKsxZJs4oCY4oG44bqLInrigbZZ////IlByb2dyYW1taW5nIFB1enpsZXMgJiBDb2RlIEdvbGYhIg)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>151</s> <s>147</s> <s>144</s> <s>143</s> 139 bytes

```java
s->{String x="\n"+s;for(int i=64,t;++i<91;)for(char c:x.toCharArray())s+=(t=c&~32)>64&t<91&t>i|c<11?c:" ";return s.replaceAll("\\s+$","");}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##pVBda8IwFH33V9yFURqqZW4izNgO8WFPE2GP6kNMo4tLk5Kk4lf96zXOvgy2Jy8J3K9zOOdu6JZ2dMHVJvuumaTWwgcV6tgCEMpxs6KMw@RaAnw6I9QaWNgkFhPfr/z3zzrqBIMJKEigtp302GztEjRXKLJkpU3oOUEk/V7bkSgSw9cuwdc2@6IG2GAXOz326cgYug8xtlESuoQF55dnnPZ7gfOAwKXixIbd7hsbIEDEcFcaBTY2vJBe7EjKEM3nNnpEbYQwqWoCv@ImtyiX0sttVG@1yCD3vhtrswVQ3JjeW8fzWJcuLvzISRWqmIWI@kD45wJ/Lv0/ucGXLLsHPzV6bWieXy88LQ8HyS0EMNYZh3ctVw93UJ9PM69u@JSyJV2czg1T1arqCw)

```java
s->{                   // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  String x="\n"+s;     //  Temp-String (equal to leading new-line + input)
  for(int i=64,        //  Index-integer `i` (starting at 64)
          t;           //  Temp-integer
      ++i<91;)         //  Loop (1) from 'A' (65) to 'Z' (90) (inclusive)
    for(char c:x.toCharArray())
                       //   Inner loop (2) over the character of the array
      s+=(t=c&~32)>64  //    If the current character as uppercase is larger than 'A'
         &t<91         //    and smaller or equal to 'Z'
         &t>i          //    and larger than the current index
         |c<11?        //    or the current character is a new-line
          c            //     Append the current character to `s`
         :             //    Else:
          " ";         //     Append a space to `s` instead
                       //   End of inner loop (2) (implicit / single-line body)
                       //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  return s             //  Return the result,
    .replaceAll("\\s+$",""); 
                       //   after we've removed all trailing spaces and new-lines
}                      // End of method
```

Answer (score 2):

## [q](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/), <s>42</s> 37 bytes

```
{(+)max[m]$(m:1+mod[.Q.a?(_)x]26)#'x}
```

-5 thanks to streetster!

---

old solution+explanation:

```
{(+)max[m]$'(m:1+mod[.Q.a?lower x;26])#'x}


{                                        }  / lambda func
                     .Q.a?lower x           / get lowercase of input (ignores non-alpha values) and find (?) their index in "a...z" (.Q.a). non-alpha values return `26`
                 mod[.Q.a?lower x;26]       / get mod 26 of each index, this returns 0 where index is 26
            (m:1+mod[.Q.a?lower x;26])      / add 1 and assign to m
            (m:1+mod[.Q.a?lower x;26])#'x   / m and x conform, so we can take (#) m copies of each (') x at corresponding indices
    max[m]$'(m:1+mod[.Q.a?lower x;26])#'x   / get max of m, and pad each ($') of right-side list to that length
 (+)                                        / transpose the char matrix
```

Comment: `{(+)max[m]$(m:1+mod[.Q.a?(_)x]26)#'x}` for 37, cant remember how I solved it when creating the question, probably very similar though!

Comment: @streetster, thanks! updated. didn't know about k's `_` , i typed `lower` in the q interpreter and got ```k){$[~t&77h>t:abs@@x;.z.s'x;19<t;.z.s@. x;~t in 10 11h;'`type;_x]}```. hence giving my answer in q haha

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
ā,{Z⁴UW1Χ∙┼
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUwMTAxJTJDJTdCWiV1MjA3NFVXMSV1MDNBNyV1MjIxOSV1MjUzQw__,inputs=UHJvZ3JhbW1pbmclMjBQdXp6bGVzJTIwJTI2JTIwQ29kZSUyMEdvbGYlMjElMjBhYmNCQQ__)

Explanation:

```
ā            push an empty array
 ,{          for each character in the input, pushing it
   Z           push the uppercase alphabet
    ⁴          push a duplicate of the character
     U         uppercase it
      W        find its index in that alphabet
       1Χ      get the maximum of that and 1
         ∙     repeat the character that many times
          ┼    append horizontally to that array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 141 bytes

```
_L;|dim g(a)┘dim H(a)[a|_SA,b,1|┘H(b)=B┘o=asc(ucase$(B))-65~o<1or o>25|o=0]g(b)=o~g(b)>p|p=g(b)}?A[p|[a|~g(d)|g(d)=g(d)-1\H(d)=@ `]?H(d)';`]?
```

Wow, this has to be the longest entry I've made using QBIC...

### Explanation

```
_L |                        Assign to num var 'a' the length of
  ;                         A$, which is read off the CMD line
dim g(a)                    Define 'g' as an array of 'a' slots. The lower-
                            case letter denotes it will store numbers.
                            g() will store if we still need to rain down the char at pos ()
                            of the input string.
┘                           Inject a linebreak in the compiled QBasic
dim H(a)                    Define H$ to be an array, also of length 'a', for strings
                            H$(x) will store what to rain down if g(x) > 0
[a|                         Run along the length of the input string
                            (QBasic: FOR b = 1 TO a STEP 1)
  _SA,b,1|┘                 Take a substring at index b on string A$, length 1 and 
                            store as B$; lift out each character one at a time
  H(b)=B┘                   Save the character in H$(x)
  o=asc(ucase$(B))-65       Take the ASCII codepoint of that substring, as uppercase 
                            minus 65. [A-Z] maps to 0-25. Save that number as 'o'
  ~o<1or o>25               IF o is not in range
  |o=0]                     THEN set o to zero (the same value as 'A/a')
  g(b)=o                    SET the number of rain-down copies to 'o'
  ~g(b)>p                   IF the number of raindowns exceeds the prvious max,
  |p=g(b)                   THEN store the new max into 'p'. This defines the rain-down depth
}                           END IF, NEXT
?A                          PRINT the original, \n
[p|                         FOR c = 1 TO max-depth 
  [a|                       FOR d = 1 to LEN(A$)
    ~g(d)                   IF the rain-down counter is positive
    |g(d)=g(d)-1            THEN decrement it by 1
    \H(d)=@ `               ELSE replace the char by a literal space in the char map
    ]                       END IF
    ?H(d)                   PRINT the character at the current pos int he char map
      ';`                   and suppress newlines
  ]                         NEXT character
?                           PRINT \n at the end of the line
```

Comment: I was going to write a QBasic answer until I realized that 26 lines of output wouldn't fit on the screen without scrolling. Does QBIC have the same limitation? If so, what are your thoughts on how that affects the validity of this solution?

Comment: @DLosc Same restriction applies to QBIC; it runs QBasic code after all. However, I feel the answer is valid - within the technical possibilities of the QBasic platform. Inputs that don't require displaying 26 lines (like `~|[abc<0>cba]|~`) show that the functionality of this is according to spec.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 47 bytes

```
[[:upcase ALPHA\index 0 max#+*]"!LF#`togrid tr]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcq9DoIwFAbQ3af4kMRBF2cmiYkyMHQHEm/6ZyOl5rZNCC9f2M5wYiL506qUYWjyX1LUaHvRtaNblF5xh6e1vl2nc9W/6k8Klp1C4qk8GnMithHGcUyQX@LDCDmVIvh45L1bLETetllHXPAMSuMdZlPt) Takes input as list of characters, and returns a list of list of characters.

```
[[:upcase ALPHA\index 0 max#+*]"!LF#`togrid tr]          input: str
 [                            ]"!                        for(char of str)
   upcase ALPHA\index                                        get index of uppercase char
                                                             in uppercase alphabet
                      0 max                                  max(0, index)
  :                        #+*                               repeat char ^ times
                                 LF#`togrid                  convert to aligned char array
                                            tr               transpose
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 106 bytes

```
foreach("\n","^B-Zb-z",(range(24)|[.+66,.+98]|implode))as$x(.;gsub("[\($x)]";" ");.)|select(.!=length*" ")
```

Expanded

```
   foreach ("\n",                            # first pattern won't match anything
            "^B-Zb-z",                       # next a, A and punctuation
            (range(24)|[.+66,.+98]|implode)  # then Bb, Cc, ...
   ) as $x (
     .
   ; gsub("[\($x)]";" ")                     # apply each pattern to input
   ; .
   )
 | select(.!=length*" ")                     # eliminate blank lines
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctNC8IgHIDxr2J/IrSmh4goRpc6dO1cW2DlnOF0@UIx/OzZOv54eJ6vDCdnpeNdp4xEpzgMWng0Qwf7EOhodTOBlBvrBL@3GCoDBVz39HyjAxTYcSMFXq5IurDFel2wxXZTJ9X1erwJ4X76wayUPt4wXCo8/ZAaSkBASkaSF1rcA2aTnRZGhnb@Dzl/bR@UNT5TaqLWVJk@hhGOv6mNYcQP)

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 181 bytes

```
	S =OUTPUT =INPUT
	U =&UCASE
	L =&LCASE
Z	S NOTANY(U L ' ') =' '	:S(Z)
N	U LEN(1) . X REM . U
	L LEN(1) . Y REM . L
R	S (X | Y) =' '	:S(R)
	S NOTANY(' ')	:F(END)
	OUTPUT =S	:(N)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCoJAEIbPu08xXXT3EgSdhD1IbRFsq7guqLcik0BdULpI776NUXmZf/iY@WbG3l1du/WeGBCJzVObgzhpDEosiMDuYiMpUdiqT1vhoE7yWJfMgoIQQg4CK4kMqzjVuKWkZhsOayggk2dMOwv@tPxSRTN0sQJeUC6OjNPlwmwn0YFJvUf8e8@QiGlOEXqfDq4ZLl336BtIn9PU1iMEsHO3Go6uva/e)

```
	S =OUTPUT =INPUT		;* read input and print it
	U =&UCASE			;* alias for uppercase letters
	L =&LCASE			;* alias for lowercase letters
Z	S NOTANY(U L ' ') =' '	:S(Z)	;* replace non-alphabet, non-space characters with space
N	U LEN(1) . X REM . U		;* get the Next uppercase letter
	L LEN(1) . Y REM . L		;* get the Next lowercase letter
R	S (X | Y) =' '	:S(R)		;* replace all those with spaces
	S NOTANY(' ')	:F(END)		;* if S is all spaces, terminate the program
	OUTPUT =S	:(N)		;* else print S and goto N
END
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 97 bytes

```julia
f(s,h=c->isletter(c)&&(c-'A')%32)=println.([s;[map(c->h(c)>i ? c : ' ',s) for i=0:maximum(h,s)]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY3LCsMgEAB/ZQk0uhBLH7cUDf2OkMNWIm7RNKiBHPLvqdeZgflugem@n6eTufPaKsM5zKXMSVpsW2mVeAu8PB@o18RLCctVjvk1RlqrM75WhmEACz0IEF1GcL8ErG99pJ3jFqWvcJqwHhpyH/KO/HE4UgM2eP4B)

Comment: This only prints one `b`, 2 `c` etc, think you need a +1 or something somewhere :)

Comment: Change the A to an @ https://tio.run/##DY3dCoMgGEBf5SPIn1GDtrtC13tEF84ZfkObqEH08s7bcw6c7@FQDWcpG0udFbqXmJzJ2USmOSFM93SmvH0@uAgR9@z2O1vStHgVqpO2VhLhBRpGoEC7xGH7RUAxjF6d6A/PbIXryuuhUW/9MXCbSQvhuhpe/g

Comment: Should be fixed now

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
î┌→♠─l∙╨"«Pò
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8cda1a06c46cf9d022ae5095&i=%22Programming+Puzzles+%26+Code+Golf%21%22&a=1)

Answer (score 1):

## [Assembly (MIPS, SPIM)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spim), 319 bytes

```
.text
.globl main
main:
lw $4 4($5)
li $2 4
syscall
li $9 65
li $11 91
li $14 122
move $12 $4
li $2 11
syscall
g:
li $4 10
syscall
addi $9 1
bge $9 $11 n
addi $8 $12 -1
l:
addi $8 1
lb $4 ($8)
beqz $4 g
blt $4 $9 e
blt $4 $11 f
addi $13 $9 32
blt $4 $13 e
bgt $4 $14 e
f:
syscall
j l
e:
li $4 32
j f
n:
li $2 10
syscall
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BbsMgEETv@xVbyYqSQ6OCSZVwzaHX/IKpMXK0mDZ22sQ/Txbq0AuamWUey/jV@xi3k71NsHUUDKFv@gHSoYF@sVKo1tVuA9RjJVHBeB8/G6LsD/i@y0IIPIg/pVBICT78WDaS@0tTiFJ1Omd8861kTdtmoADjbBKJOSzxPqNe@QVdEjYmMdbVfgPGfs/JODA0JcEAWzSTuqUn6jSq5f@sThfdYhSbTpelzkhgn8ty6cycQT8/VJaPMZ4uwV0a7/vB4ek6z2RHXOExtBY/AnUvDw)

almost positive this can be golfed further, (might be able to use mod instead of a bunch of branches, idk) but i'm not complaining. Takes the string as a command line argument. most of the registers are used for magic ascii numbers, though $9 and $8 update - $9 is the current iteration, starting at 65 (a). $8 starts at the beginning of the string, then iterates over the string until reaching a null terminator. characters that are no longer valid are replaced with '32' or space. Prints a single trailing newline, on the last line.

The output is padded - that is, if the input string is 5 characters long, each printed row will also be 5 characters long, even if this means the last few bytes in a row are space characters. 
or more practically: "Faa"=>
`"Faa"
 "F  "
 "F  "
 "F  "
 "F  "
 "F  "`
The instructions did not specify if we had to trim each row to the shortest possible or if this behavior was allowed. If the trimmed variant is desired I can mark this non-competing.

Comment: one cool aside: flipping the contents of e and f in the code will result in [stalagmites](https://tio.run/##RU9BbsIwELzvK7ZShOBQVDsGga89cOULceNYqdZxIaGUfN5du8G9WDOzO7Pj8av3MW4n@zPB1lEwhL7pB0iPBrpjpVCtq90GqMdKooLxMX40RJkfcb/LQAg8ij@kUEgJPnxbJpL9i1OIYnU6a7z5VrSmbXOgAONsAilzWORDjnrlC7ooTEzKWFeHDRh7mRNxYGhKgANswZzULT5Rp1Et/2d1WnQLUUy6ZzvesroU/ESCQT8/U4rHGM/X4K6N9/3g8HybZ7IjrvA9tBZPgbqXXw " - the code will print the line at the top, then grow from the bottom up, as if the text dripped down to the ground and built up over time. Did that by accident first and wondered what I did wrong.

Comment: Nice! No requirement to trim the strings so all good on that front :)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 7, 110 Bytes

```
$t.="
";for($i=66;$i<90&&trim($t);){echo$t;$t=preg_replace('~[^\n'.chr($i).'-Z'.chr(32+$i++).'-z]~', ' ',$t);}
```

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f3c6de99ab25ce206cdf944db400d6bb51e3f7b)

### Ungolfed

Input given in $t

```
$t.="
";

for($i=66;$i<90&&trim($t);){
    echo$t;
    $t=preg_replace('~[^\n'.chr($i).'-Z'.chr(32+$i++).'-z]~', ' ',$t);
}
```

Comment: nice answer. Do host it on http://tio.run so people can verify your answer.

Comment: @Razetime; Thanks foir the feedback. Done. @Titus: Thanks for showing a simpler alternative to tio.run. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 23 bytes

```
PaFi,26P{z@?LCa>i?as}Ma
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExCoAwDAXQq/wDODk4qqA4KRYrOAcJNFBb0S5VPHt875RT1dAgRVmZ92mbsaNaGrq/iVS1c3GPnhJjIREJBWw8GDZRRn9lbE48Y06OrxsDs8fqGIYk/A)

### Explanation

```
PaFi,26P{z@?LCa>i?as}Ma
Pa                      Print the original string
  Fi,26                 loop with variable i across range 0-26 
                     Ma Map the input to the following function
        {z@?LCa>i?as}   Replace any symbols with index lesser than i with a space
       P                Print the mapped string
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

```
T' m?SRȯ-64ca;√
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P0RdIdc@OOjEel0zk@RE60cds/7//x9QlJ9elJibm5mXrhBQWlWVk1qsoKbgnJ@SquCen5OmCAA)

repeat each character, then transpose-pad.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ä1|Ḟ×ðƬ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

##### Explanation

```python
Ä1|Ḟ×ðƬ  # Implicit input
Ä        # Get the 1-based index in the alphabet
         # for each character in the input string
 1|      # Replace 0s (non-alphabets) with 1s
   Ḟ×    # Multiply elementwise with the input
     ðƬ  # Transpose with filler space
         # Implicit output, joined on newlines
```