# Repeat the Nth elements

Tags: code-golf, string

<sub>We haven't had a [string](/questions/tagged/string) question for a while (5 days to be precise), so let's go for one.</sub>

Given a string `s` and a positive integer `n`, take every `n`th element of `s`, repeat it `n` times, and put it back into `s`.

For example, if `n = 3` and `s = "Hello, World!"`, every third character is `Hl r!`. You then repeat each character `n` times to produce `HHHlll   rrr!!!`. You then replace the original letters with the repeated versions to produce the final product of `HHHellllo,   Worrrld!!!`

You are to accomplish this task in the shortest code possible in your language!

## Rules

- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins
- `n` is guaranteed to be smaller than the length of `s` and greater than 0
- The first character of `s` is where the `n`th characters are taken from, and is always repeated `n` times
- `s` will only consist of printable ASCII (code points `0x20 (space)` to `0x7E (~)`)

## Test cases

```
s, n => output

"Hello, World!", 3 => "HHHellllo,   Worrrld!!!"
"Code golf", 1 => "Code golf"
"abcdefghijklm", 10 => "aaaaaaaaaabcdefghijkkkkkkkkkklm"
"tesTing", 6 => "ttttttesTingggggg"
"very very very long string for you to really make sure that your program works", 4 => "vvvvery    veryyyy verrrry loooong sssstrinnnng foooor yoooou toooo reaaaally    makeeee surrrre thhhhat yyyyour    proggggram    workkkks"
```

Comment: Can we take the input `s` as a character array?

Comment: "*and put it back into `s`*" <- is this a strict requirement (overwriting the original string) or ist it ok to just output the final result?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes you can

Comment: @FelixPalmen that was simply how I explained it. You can use any method you want

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing good, thanks, already did that.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
Ḣs×
```

Input is taken as **s, n**.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjkXFh6f/LzY63P6oaU3k//9KHkCJfB2F8PyinBRFJR0FYx0FJef8lFSF9PycNCDfEMhPTEpOSU1Lz8jMys7JBYkZAAVLUotDMvPSgVwzAA)

#### How it works

```
Ḣs×  Main link. Argument: s, n

Ḣ    Head; yield s.
     This pops the list, leaving [n] as the main link's argument.
 s   Split s into chunks of length n.
  ×  Multiply each chunk by [n], repeating its first element n times.
```

Comment: Isn't it actually 6 bytes in UTF-8 encoding? `E1 B8 A2 73 C3 97`

Comment: In UTF-8, yes. However, Jelly uses a [custom code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), where each of the characters it understands takes up only a single byte.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>6</s>  5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 byte thanks to leaky Nun (use Python's string multiplication.)

```
×Jm¥¦
```

A full program, accepting two command line arguments, the string and the number, and printing the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wdK/cQ0sPLfv//78HUCRfRyE8vygnRfG/MQA)**

#### How?

```
×Jm¥¦ - Main link: list of characters, s; number, n   e.g. ['g','o','l','f','e','r'], 2
    ¦ - sparse application:
   ¥  - ...to indices: last two links as a dyad:
 J    -      range of length of s                          [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  m   -      modulo slicing by n (every nth entry)         [1,3,5]
×    - ...action: multiply  ["gg",'o',"ll",'f',"ee",'r']
      - implicit print                                 >>> ggollfeer
```

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wdK/cQ0sPLfv//78HUCRfRyE8vygnRfG/MQA)?

Comment: Yep tried `x` forgot `×`; thanks.

Comment: Isn't it actually 8 bytes in UTF-8 encoding? `C3 97 4A 6D C2 A5 C2 A6`

Comment: @CoDEmanX Uses Jelly's custom [code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Comment: @MDXF thanks for fielding!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(s)(n)`.

```js
s=>n=>s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>c.repeat(i%n?1:n))
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>n=>s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>c.repeat(i%n?1:n))

console.log(f("Hello, World!")(3))
console.log(f("Code golf")(1))
console.log(f("abcdefghijklm")(10))
console.log(f("tesTing")(6))
console.log(f("very very very long string for you to really make sure that your program works")(4))
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>84</s> 82 bytes

```cs
n=>m=>{var s="";for(int i=0;i<n.Length;)s+=new string(n[i],i++%m<1?m:1);return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xa8MwEIVn@1cchoCEHdMsHSrLHQqZUii00CFkEKrsHkQnuFMSSvBvd13SIev7vvd4XtY@cZj90YnAG6eRXYRrWUh2GT2cE37Bq0NSkhlp3B/A8Sh6UcqieP@RHGK7PZHvbryB@wwpN3ADfQ8D2JlsH21/PTsGsVVlhsRqsQDtg8GO2l2gMX8bLbWlcPnvKtrjocG6XsVu8xyfNtpwyCcmEDPN5u7JSyJJx9B@MuawQwpqUFUO8rGsVFo9av1nT@U0/wI)

Comment: You can save a byte by removing `i++` and changing `n[i],i%m<1?m:1` to `n[i],i++%m<1?m:1`.

Comment: You can save another byte by currying the inputs: `n=>m=>...`

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @Emigna

```
ôʒć²×ì?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f8wNWFiMWX//8O0ypLEh8Kyw5fDrD///0hlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEKMw)

#### Explanation

```
ôʒć²×ì?    Arguments s, n  ("Hello, World!", 3)
ô          Split s into pieces of n  (["Hel", "lo,", ...])
 ʒ         Filter (used as foreach)
  ć          Extract head  ("Hel" -> "el", "H" ...)
   ²×ì       Repeat n times and prepend  ("el", "H" -> "HHHel" ...)
      ?      Print without newline
```

Comment: Save a byte with `ôʒć²×ì?`

Comment: @Emigna thanks, I knew there must be a way to get rid of the closing `}`

Comment: Weird use of filter when it isn't using the result but it actually makes a difference...

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn, yep filter is still the better foreach in 05AB1E

Comment: @kalsowerus `vy` is one foreach, `ε` is another. Oddly enough, `ε` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 44 bytes

```
s=>n=>"".join(s[i]*(i%n?1:n)for i:0..len(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclBCoAgEADAr5gQrBFSdBOsaz/oEN1S2JBdWf2/OdfJwpWpRd@K38nvWtuPkaDc@EyAIx2rIxNZFLrF2hR6GdOyIFWIoM@QEs/qYknvoA1sPX8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>54</strike> 53 bytes

**Edit:** Saved 1 byte thanks to [@Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47120/rod)

```python
f=lambda x,n,i=0:x[i:]and[1,n][i%n<1]*x[i]+f(x,n,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZHNbsIwEITP5CmWSJWg@EBa1ANqTr3wAJV6iKzKJM5PcWxkG0qePp0NFfkOsbIz65ko5yG2zr6MY50b1R8rRTdhRZdv97ei20tlqyITVhbdk33P5DOGclOvJs8mW49Rh/hdqqAD5VQkiyI9aGOcoC/nTbVMBb0KSg8Hnk5zYsWztlymUvDGh6s0Nc7UcGdwz@93XR3LStdN2/2cTM@eLUzqwaw@gO2@inqfnW2w9IadOHEfTfy7rtoPND@Msw2F6OGi2nka3IWiI6@VMQP16qQpXLym2KrIoqezd41XPf06fwoI2yHsCvg2wCfgE3AA4AzAMYCTAIcBzgMcCTgVcDDgbMDxgBsALgG4B@AqgNuAkMpEJgl/iRJHUVJnaf5t@2RxRoW4qldQ15TnVK7HPw)

Comment: you can swap `x[i]` and `[1,n][i%n<1]` to save a space

Answer (score 3):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 25 bytes

```
/
KI /!Iw?&.?t&O?&wWOI.h%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1@fy9tTQV/Rs9xeTc@@RM3fXq083N9TL0P1/39jLo/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEUA)

#### Explanation

```
/         Switch to Ordinal.
I         Read first line of input (i.e. n).
/         Switch to Cardinal.
!         Convert input to its integer value and store it on the tape.
I         Read first character from input string.
w         Push current IP address onto the return address stack. This
          effectively marks the beginning of the main loop.

  ?         Retrieve n.
  &.        Duplicate current character n times (once more than we need,
            but who cares about a clean stack...).
  ?t        Retrieve n and decrement.
  &O        Output n-1 copies of the current character.
  ?         Retrieve n.
  &w        Push the current IP address onto the return address stack n
            times. This marks the beginning of a loop that is executed n 
            times.

    W         Discard one copy of the return address from the stack,
              effectively decrementing the loop counter.
    O         Output the last character. On the first iteration, this is
              the final copy of the repeated character, otherwise it's just
              the single character we read on the last iteration.
    I         Read a character for the next iteration.
    .h%       Compute c % (c+1) on that character, which is a no-op for
              for valid characters, but terminates the program at EOF when
              c becomes -1.

K         Jump to the address on top of the return address stack. As long
          as there are still copies of the address from the inner loop, we
          perform another iteration of that, otherwise we jump back to the
          beginning of the outer loop.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>82</s> <s>76</s> 75 bytes

```r
function(s,n)cat(rep(S<-el(strsplit(s,'')),c(n,rep(1,n-1))+!seq(S)),sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxEsIgDADQ3a@gXZqcYei51t29g3Ol4eQuQk1w8OsR5/e0SXropl94cX2W3fAU3eJb/ORQU8lglDFsFZQPWBfPAlbVDkm10zQhUoBMf50p@xnxPBi/Ye1gfFz7aBHGG4sUcveisg8juQu2Hw)

A function; takes a string `s` and an integer `n`, and prints the repeated version to stdout.

Explanation:

```r
function(s,n){
 S <- el(strsplit(s,""))                  # characters
 r     <- c(n,rep(1,n-1))                 # [n, 1, 1,...,1], length n
 repeats <- r+!seq(S)                     # extends R to length of S
 cat(rep(S, repeats), sep="")             # print out
}
```

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 55 bytes

```r
function(S,n)cat(rep(S,c(n,rep(1,n-1))+!seq(S)),sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcmxCoAwDATQX7GZEoyDuOru7uAstQVB0trq99cUyvHgjkvFd/NQ/Cf2vYLgxkL2eDG5qN2icG0jyzAS9Sa7Bzcizi4uAFQ8WoQVGJy6m6BqOrW3ndp3KgPEE5Uf)

Same algorithm as above, but with `S` taken as a list of individual characters.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 51 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$n)-join($a|%{($_,("$_"*$n))[!($i++%$n)]})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRRyVPUzcrPzMPyK5RrdZQidfRUFKJV9ICimtGK2qoZGprqwLZsbWa////d9BQ91DXUU8F4hwozgdiEFQA4nAovwgqlwLEiuqa/40B)

Takes input as a `char`-array `$a` and the number `$n`. Loops through `$a` and each iteration either outputs the current letter `$_` or the current letter multiplied by `$n`, based on an index into a pseudo-ternary. The index chooses between the two based off of incrementing `$i` and then modulo `$n`. Those letters are then `-join`ed back together and the string is left on the pipeline; output is implicit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,n,i=0:x[i:]and n**(i%n<1)*x[i]+f(x,n,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZHNboMwEITP4Sk2SJWA@JAoVQ@onHrJA1TqIUKVA@anMXZkO2l4ejpLqvAdsNiZ9QziMobOmv00NYWWw6mWdBdG9MU2vx/7vJSmJpNlSf9i3ndphlm5aZLZstmlU1A@fFfSK08FHaPVMT4ora2gL@t0vY4F7QXFhwNP5zmx4lhbr@NS8MaHrRW1Vjdw7@Be3h@6PFW1atqu/znrgT1bmOSTRX0C22MV9T5702LpDTth5jGa@XfdlBtpeWhrWvLBwUWNdTTaKwVLTkmtRxrkWZG/OkWhk4FFRxdnWycH@rXu7BH2irAb4NsAn4BPwAGAMwDHAE4CHAY4D3Ak4FTAwYCzAccDbgC4BOAegKsAbgN8XEZlFPGXSHESFfWGlt@WR6sLKoSkSaCmVBRUpdMf)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
ËùDV*EvV
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=y/lEVipFdlY=&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEiIDM=)

#### Explanation

```
 Ë    ùDV*EvV
UmDE{DùDV*EvV}   Ungolfed
                 Implicit: U = s, V = n
UmDE{        }   Replace each char D and (0-)index E in U by this function:
          EvV      Take 1 if the index is divisible by V; 0 otherwise.
        V*         Multiply this by V. This gives V for every Vth index; 0 for others.
     DùD           Pad D with itself to this length. This gives V copies of D for every
                   Vth index; 1 copy of D for others.
                 Implicit: output last expression
```

I have to credit the idea to use `ù` to [@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)'s answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144898/42545). I don't know that I ever would have thought of it myself...

Comment: You see now why was so keen to see string padding added :) Nice solution. I was trying to get something to work with `ë`, for poops & giggles, but failed miserably!

Answer (score 2):

## J, 17 bytes

```
(#@]$[,1#~<:@[)#]
```

- `(...) # ]` everything in parens creates the string for J's built in "copy" verb.  So, eg, if the left argument is 3, it creates the string `3 1 1` repeated as needed to equal the number of characters in the right arg `]`, which contains the string.  Which is to say, `#` solves the problem directly, assuming we can give it the correct left argument: `4` should be `4 1 1 1` repeated, and so on.
- Examining `#@]$[,1#~<:@[`, we see it uses J's shape verb `$` in the middle -- that's the main verb of this phrase...
- To the left of `$` is `#@]`, meaning the length `#` of the right arg `]`.
- To the right of `$` is `[,1#~<:@[`, a 5 verb train.  The first train executed is...
- `1#~<:@[`, which means 1 copied `#~` (passive form of copy) one less than `<:` the left arg `[`.  This result is passed to the final fork:
- `[, ...` meaning take the left arg, and append the result we just calculated, which is a string of `1`s.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/zWUHWJVonUMletsrByiNZVj/2tyKekpqKfZWqkr6CjUWimkFXNxpSZn5CsYGiikKagnJiWnpKalZ2RmZefkqkNlQBLJ@SmpCun5OWnq/wE)

Comment: `]#~[^0=(|i.@#)` for 14 bytes

Comment: That's quite clever.  Your improvements to my posts are the best part of this site for me.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, <s>37</s>, 29 +1 (-p) bytes

-8 bytes thanks to Tom's comment.

```
$n=<>;s/./"@-"%$n?$&:$&x$n/ge
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lz9bGzrpYX09fyUFXSVUlz15FzUpFrUIlTz899f9/j9ScnHwdhfD8opwURS7jf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

Comment: Can't think of a better approach right now, but I came up with a few ideas: `$n=<>;` instead of the `BEGIN` block and have `n` on the next line of input and replace `$-[0]` with `"@-"` since only the first number is evaluated in comparison. Also, if you take input of `n` via `-i` you can just use `$^I` instead of declaring and using `$n`, but since this is non-standard it might not fly... :)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>100</s> 76 bytes

```java
s->n->{int i,k=0;for(char c:s)for(i=k++%n<1?n:1;i-->0;)System.out.print(c);}
```

-24 bytes thanks to *@OliverGrégoire*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jZHBasMwDIbvfQqtMEhoY1o2dmjajFEY22GnDnYoPbiOkzpxrCA7HaH02TNnlA3GAgVjbCR9@vWr4EceYS1NkZad0NxaeOPKnEYA1nGnBBQ@gzVOaZY1RjiFhj1fHktx4LTdTf/LWaOxTSVp@WqczCUlCQhYdTZKTJSclHGgpuVqFmdIQY8BsbBh/1GrcjK5Ncv5o1nMYxVFySwON611smLYOFaTLw5EGJ@72Kv0p2722gu96D2iSqHyMwQb51Pz7Q542M8DIBiva90G4xepNU7hA0mnN2PmcO0VPBHxNghDxoWQtQvuwvi76m9vbYJL5Ie3xlRCjjobYs2vZ/G9SGWWH1RR6mqQN7se6KR99z4MoR6uJx0ltfB7aTS5d703GfzmoMUGHAJJrnXrV1BKsA1JcAfu@iBBTZgTr@ATqbRDgu6/255H5@4L)

```java
s->n->{                    // Method with char-array and int parameters and no return-type
  int i,k=0;               //  Index-integers
  for(char c:s)            //  Loop (1) over the characters of the input array
    for(i=k++%n<1?         //   If `k` is divisible by the input `n`:
         n                 //    Change `i` to `n`
        :                  //   Else:
         1;                //    Change `i` to 1
        i-->0;)            //   Inner loop (2) from `i` down to 0
      System.out.print(c); //    And print the current character that many times
                           //   End of inner loop (2) (implicit / single-line body)
                           //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
}                          // End of method
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't see there was already a submission so I deleted mine. Here's it, shortened to 76 bytes: `n->s->{int i,k=0;for(char c:s)for(i=k++%n<1?n:1;i-->0;)System.out.print(c);}` (with a `char[]`, instead of `String`.)

Comment: Rule of the thumb, if you have to declare exactly one String that will be returned, it's shorter to just print it out.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Oops.. Yes, I know that rule of thumb, just forgot to apply it this time.. And thanks for the saved bytes!

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 61 + 18 = 79 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;
n=>m=>string.Concat(n.Select((c,i)=>new string(c,i%m<1?m:1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHBS8MwFMbP7V/xHAgJzOJQPNi1HgbiQUGYsIN4iOlrF5fkaZJuFNnfXlM6cLdecvi@75eP9570V5Ic9q1XtoF15wOa7FnZnzyVWngPr44aJwz8pokPIigJe1IVvAhlmQ8uUu8fIFzjeYykSXL64rG1cjn6czjXlA1zGI2yhBqK3halKcpRylZkpQjMZmvUKANjcq54UVo8nKBBuDTLxYO5X3DO@/ysNMKeNGYbpwLGIZDVbPaEWhNsyOnqYsbZDef5BLGiCqEhXcf4YjouPmWFdbNVXzttBuR6mgno3@IwMX03Hd6j6@D/0RQvNS4DanLQUQuBwKHQugMjdgi@dQhhK8JgOvg@3fBAbudj5@3QmSbH9Nj/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) routine, 50 bytes

```
A0 01 84 97 88 84 9E 84 9F B1 FB F0 20 A4 9F 91 FD C6 97 D0 10 A6 FF CA F0
05 C8 91 FD D0 F8 84 9F A5 FF 85 97 E6 9E A4 9E E6 9F D0 DC A4 9F 91 FD 60
```

This is a position-independent subroutine expecting a pointer to the input string (0-terminated aka C-string) in `$fb`/`$fc`, a pointer to the output buffer in `$fd`/`$fe` and the count (`n`) in `$ff`. It uses simple indexing, so it's limited to a maximum output length of 255 characters (+ 0 byte) due to the 8bit architecture.

**Explanation (commented disassembly):**

```
 .rep:
A0 01       LDY #$01            ; init counter to next repetition sequence
84 97       STY $97
88          DEY                 ; init read and write index
84 9E       STY $9E             ; (read)
84 9F       STY $9F             ; (write)
 .rep_loop:
B1 FB       LDA ($FB),Y         ; read next character
F0 20       BEQ .rep_done       ; 0 -> finished
A4 9F       LDY $9F             ; load write index
91 FD       STA ($FD),Y         ; write next character
C6 97       DEC $97             ; decrement counter to nex rep. seq.
D0 10       BNE .rep_next       ; not reached yet -> next iteration
A6 FF       LDX $FF             ; load repetition counter
 .rep_seqloop:
CA          DEX                 ; and decrement
F0 05       BEQ .rep_seqdone    ; if 0, no more repetitions
C8          INY                 ; increment write index
91 FD       STA ($FD),Y         ; write character
D0 F8       BNE .rep_seqloop    ; and repeat for this sequence
 .rep_seqdone:
84 9F       STY $9F             ; store back write index
A5 FF       LDA $FF             ; re-init counter to next ...
85 97       STA $97             ; ... repetition sequence
 .rep_next:
E6 9E       INC $9E             ; increment read index
A4 9E       LDY $9E             ; load read index
E6 9F       INC $9F             ; increment write index
D0 DC       BNE .rep_loop       ; jump back (main loop)
 .rep_done:
A4 9F       LDY $9F             ; load write index
91 FD       STA ($FD),Y         ; and write terminating0-byte there
60          RTS                 ; done.
```

**Example C64 machine code program using it**:

This is a program in [ca65](http://cc65.github.io/doc/ca65.html)-style assembler for the C64 using this routine (imported as `rep`):

```
REP_IN          = $fb
REP_IN_L        = $fb
REP_IN_H        = $fc

REP_OUT         = $fd
REP_OUT_L       = $fd
REP_OUT_H       = $fe

REP_N           = $ff

.import         rep


.segment "LDADDR"
                .word   $c000

.code
                jsr     $aefd           ; consume comma
                jsr     $ad9e           ; evaluate expression
                sta     REP_IN_L        ; store string length
                jsr     $b6a3           ; free string
                ldy     #$00            ; loop over string
readloop:       cpy     REP_IN_L        ; end of string?
                beq     termstr         ; then jump to 0-terminate string
                lda     ($22),y         ; read next character
                sta     in,y            ; store in input buffer
                iny                     ; next
                bne     readloop
termstr:        lda     #$00            ; load 0 byte
                sta     in,y            ; store in input buffer

                jsr     $b79b           ; read 8bit unsigned int
                stx     REP_N           ; store in `n`
                lda     #<in            ; (
                sta     REP_IN_L        ;   store pointer to
                lda     #>in            ;   to input string
                sta     REP_IN_H        ; )
                lda     #<out           ; (
                sta     REP_OUT_L       ;   store pointer to
                lda     #>out           ;   output buffer
                sta     REP_OUT_H       ; )
                jsr     rep             ; call function

                ldy     #$00            ; output result
outloop:        lda     out,y
                beq     done
                jsr     $ffd2
                iny
                bne     outloop
done:           rts


.bss
in:             .res    $100
out:            .res    $100
```

**[Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"repn.prg":"data:;base64,AMAg/a4gnq2F+yCjtqAAxPvwCLEimXbAyND0qQCZdsAgm7eG/6l2hfupwIX8qXaF/anBhf4gRMCgALl2wfAGINL/yND1YKABhJeIhJ6En7H78CCkn5H9xpfQEKb/yvAFyJH90PiEn6X/hZfmnqSe5p/Q3KSfkf1g"%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"repn.prg"%7D%7D)**

**Usage:** `sys49152,"[s]",[n]`, e.g. `sys49152,"Hello, World!",3`

**Important:** If the program was load from disk (like in the online demo), issue a `new` command first! This is necessary because loading a machine program trashes some C64 BASIC pointers.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>51</s> 46 bytes

Thanks @Laikoni for saving me 5 bytes!

```hs
n&s=do(m,c)<-zip[0..]s;c<$[0..(n-1)*0^mod m n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVC7TsNAEOz9FYOFkjNygiMQRbCrNFBQgUSBAjrs9QPfw7o7E4WfN2s3aVYzO6Pd2W2l70mpaTIrX1RW6LRM8s1fN3xk2@3RP5b59YyE2eySm@xT2woa5jhp2RkU0HJ4@YIYXGcCthhNOTp3hlglzAbpPM1AdYY8ijxHQ@FgTSATfBQt@iLyJOFIVjCjTrEgH1yC/R7i2YT0NfCCJomAU0uOIGbf4ijgB2kgbos11skybLoD4ic@yqZ4t05VV3G049bBVoTGqppphlh@lxXVTdv99ErH0QM7Avk33hNH90x@iQ@5FGVNM4diHbV1ONsRwc5ZlTrzH3qCHzlaaGWYRYfB2cZJjZN1vY//AQ)

#### Explanation/Ungolfed

The operator `c <$ [a..b]` replaces each element of the list `[a,a+1...b]` by `c` - so it's just a golfed `replicate`:

```hs
do(m,c)<-zip[0..]s;                                  -- with all (m,c) in the enumerated ([(0,a),(1,b)..]) input string, replace with
                   replicate (1 + (n-1)*0^mod m n) c -- either n or 1 times the character c (note that the list begins with 0, that's where the 1+ comes from)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to Luis Mendo!*

```
tq:ghY"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v6TQKj0jUun/f2MudY/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEV1AA)

Takes input as `n` and then `S` as a string/char array.

```
    % (implicit input)
    % stack: n
t   % duplicate
    % stack: n n
q   % decrement
    % stack: n n-1
:   % range
    % stack: n [1 2 ... n-1]
g   % convert to logical (nonzero->1, zero->0)
    % stack: n [1 1 ... 1]
h   % horizontal concatenate
    % stack: [n 1 1 ... 1]
Y"  % run-length decoding, taking the string as first input and recycling 
    % the lengths [n 1 1 ... 1] as needed
    % (implicit output as string)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
lambda s,n:''.join(c*[1,n][i%n<1]for i,c in enumerate(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc7BTsMwDAbg@57CTEJtUYQoTBwmxoULD4DEocsha500axJPTgrq05dEPXCJ5O@3Y9@WNFJ4XvXpvDrlL4OCKMKxqh6vZEPdP3StCLKz9@GtlZoYrOjBBsAwe2SVsI5Ns5Ygj5WgO@@6/Sc6RwK@id1wtxfwIkXhDxoQDDmdqd1IXfoBtRntdXK@8NPmCeOXDSbL6wY/yAv8P46CgZg490DZvtAMiYBRObeAVxNCnBkhjSqVkOHGZFh5@CWeYv73IOVxl9WGBF0@Xorq9F4J0HUumvUP)

Comment: Would indexing into the string rather than using `enumerate` be shorter?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing i would have to use `range(len())` in the end would be longer

Comment: [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##Rc7BTsMwDAbg@57CTEJtowgNmDhMGhcuPAASh66HrHXSrEk8OSmoT18S9cAlkr/fjn1f0kjhZdXny@qUvw4Kogynqnq6kQ11L4IQByFq@xgaTQxW9mADYJg9skpYx6ZZS5CnStBedu3@E50jCd/EbnjYS3jtZOEPGhAMOZ3peSN17QfUZrS3yfnCh80Txi8bTJa3DX6QF/h/HAUDMXHugbJ9oRkSAaNybgGvJoQ4M0IaVSohw53JsPLwSzzF/O@x6067rDYkaPPxnazO75UEXeeiWf8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
Ｎθ⪫ＥＳ⎇﹪κθι×ιθω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HckxDsIwDEDRvacImy2lE2MvAEhFSCAxhzYCCzdu3QTE6U1g/O8Pj6CDBDbbp7nkY5luUWHBrjkppQwHoQR9mOG/z7niHdC7S9QU9AO9jIUFnt4tVakOmuIK9Gus8kbszHaRWby7ivK4abbWvqxd@Qs) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the order `n`, `s`.

Comment: For some reason the TIO link has the arguments reversed. It was also for an older version of Charcoal; the `-sl` argument has since been renamed to `-l`. Current Charcoal also has the `StringMap` function which would save two bytes as it makes the `Join` unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 13 bytes

```
"aDJòylÀpÀll
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/X0Ip0cXr8KbKnMMNBYcbcnL@/zfm8kjNycnXUQjPL8pJUQQA)

This is a really dumb workaround. `òlhÀälÀlÀ<M-->l` should work, but I can't for the life of me understand why, especially since manually doing `lhÀälÀlÀ<M-->l` repeated a bunch of times *does* work.

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 1822 6144 4af2 796c c070 c06c 6c         ."aDJ.yl.p.ll
```

Explanation:

```
<C-x>               " Decrement the number
       D            " Delete that number...
     "a             "   Into register 'a'
        J           " Remove the blank line
         ò          " Recursively...
          yl        "   Yank the letter under the cursor
            Àp      "   And paste it 'a' times
              Àl    "   Move 'a' times to the right ('l' for right)
                l   "   Move to the right one more time
                    " (implicit) end the loop
```

Comment: `'l' for right` ... I'm guessing that's a holdover Vim thing? Otherwise ... *why*?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork yeah `l` is right in vim.  it might be orthographically backwards, but it's geometrically correct: `l` is the rightmost letter key of the middle row.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Right.  I made it right.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
s*Vzm^Q!d%Uz
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%2aVzm%5EQ%21d%25Uz&input=4%0Avery+very+very+long+string+for+you+to+really+make+sure+that+your+program+works&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 71 bytes

```
""<>s[[i]]~t~If[i~Mod~#2==1,#2,1]~(t=Table)~{i,Tr[1^(s=Characters@#)]}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcwxS8RAEIbh3l8xJiB3sIU5xcqVg2u0ECwCFmGFuWSzWbPJyOycEsT96zFXXZqveB/4BpTODii@xtnpOcsen2JVeWOSpJe28umVmpTvtC5UvlOFSRvRJR6D3aZfr0quio9N1IcOGWuxHPf51vzdzG/sR4G9q7JnGwIpeCcOzXWm7szVxQ7UWHAU2kxBsQY81o1tXec/@zCc8XatYmPpR7f0h3X@tjzBZQKNDqIs7KAlholOIARsMYQJBuwtxBNbkA7ljAxfTI5xgB/iPi7v92ae/wE)

saved -2 bytes by listening to user202729

Comment: I think `Map` over `Characters` may be shorter.

Comment: @user202729 ok! -2 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 58 bytes

Working on golfing it down.

I know there are already other Python answers, but I thought I'd post this one too seeing as it scores pretty well compared to the others, despite being a full function and not a lambda.

Takes input as function parameters, and prints to `STDOUT`.

```python
def f(s,n,i=0):
 for c in s:print(end=[c,c*n][i%n<1]);i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcG9CoAgEADgvae4hEDrhqKtcu8NGqTJHzqQM9Slp7fve7/6JF5bcz5AkAUZSc9q6yCkDBaIoWxvJq7Ss9PGoh35NjTwsdxqp0kvLUhx@hgTwpVydL1AWFX7AQ)

For one byte less (57), I coded a lambda, however similar answers have already been posted by other users:

```python
lambda s,n:''.join([c,c*n][i%n<1]for i,c in enumerate(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak (BrainHack)](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 122 + 3 (`-A`) = 125 bytes

I am sure this is too long, but I spent quite a while looking and couldn't find any improvements.

```
([]){{}([(([{}]<>)<{({}<<>(({})<>)>())}{}{}>)<{({}<<>({}<>)>())}{}>]<>)([][()])}({}{}<>){({}{(<()>)}{}[()])}{}{({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzNCsJADIRfxfY0AT15DYHe@gYelj30R1BcWug15NljoiASmJD5ZjIf03N7TMvLHaWSqqEARa2yECvUmAWxKG4BkWnMHwr9AclSvCmgSoZMhpFJBYMkM1@WzgeyhLr7ZfCr9@O9tf18uu1HW7v@DQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
vX‚RNIÖèy×?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/LOJRw6wgP8/D0w6vqDw83f7/f4/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEUuYwA)

**Explanation**

```
v             # for each letter in the input string
       è      # index into
 X‚           # the list [input_int,1]
   R          # reversed
    NIÖ       # with letter_index % input_int == 0
        y×    # repeat the current letter this many times
          ?   # print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>23</s> 19 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{,/(1|y*~y!!#x)#'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v1pHX8OwplKrrlJRUblCU1m9ojZaySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVHJ2jj2/38A)

**Examples:**

```
> {,/(1|y*~y!!#x)#'x}["Hello, World!";3]
"HHHellllo,   Worrrld!!!"
> {,/(1|y*~y!!#x)#'x}["Code golf";1]
"Code golf"
> {,/(1|y*~y!!#x)#'x}["abcdefghijklm";10]
"aaaaaaaaaabcdefghijkkkkkkkkkklm"
```

**Explanation:**

```
{,/(1|y*~y!!#x)#'x} / the solution
{                 } / lambda function with x and y as implicit parameters
   (          )     / do everything in brackets together
            #x      / count x, #"Hello, World!" -> 13
           !        / til, !13 -> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
         y!         / y modulo, 3!0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 -> 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0
        ~           / not, ~0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 -> 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
      y*            / multiply by y, 3*1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 -> 3 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 3
    1|              / min of 1 and, 1|3 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 3 -> 3 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 3
                #'x / take each parallel, 1 2 3#'"abc" -> "a", "bb", "ccc"
 ,/                 / flatten the list, "a", "bb", "ccc" -> "abbccc"
```

**Notes:**

- -4 bytes with different approach

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 71 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that take input from range `[A1:B1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vba
For i=1To[Len(A1)]:[C1]=i:?[Rept(Mid(A1,C1,1),B1^(Mod(C1,B1)=1))];:Next
```