# How compute WPA key?

Tags: code-golf

WPA2, the actual encryption standard that secures all modern wifi networks, has been **cracked**... This challenge has nothing to do with the way that the WPA2 was cracked, however is is about computing the 64-digit hexadecimal key that corresponds to a given WPA-PSK pass-phrase.

A wireless network with WPA-PSK encryption requires a pass-phrase to be entered to get access to the network. Most wireless drivers accept the pass-phrase as a string of at most 63 characters, and internally convert the pass-phrase to a 256-bit key. However, some systems also allow the key to be entered directly in the form of 64 hexadecimal digits. So the challenge is to calculate the 64-digit hexadecimal key that corresponds to a given pass-phrase.

The hexadecimal key is computed from the pass-phrase and the network **SSID** (an SSID is a unique ID that consists of 32 characters).

**Details of the calculation**

For WPA-PSK encryption, the binary key is derived from the pass-phrase according to the following formula: `Key = PBKDF2(pass-phrase, SSID, 4096, 256)`

The function `PBKDF2` is a standardized method to derive a key from a pass-phrase.
It is specified in [RFC2898](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt) with a clear explanation on how to compute it.
The function needs an underlying pseudo-random function.
In the case of WPA, the underlying function is `HMAC-SHA1`.

`SHA1` is a function that computes a 160-bit hash from an arbitrary amount of input data.
It is clearly explained in [RFC3174](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3174.txt).
`HMAC` is a standardized method to turn a cryptographic hash function into a keyed message authentication function.
It is specified in [RFC2104](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104).

To summarize, the key derivation process involves iterating a `HMAC-SHA1` function 4096 times, and then doing that again to produce more key bits.

**Inputs**

- SSID a string of at most 32 characters (e.g. `stackexchange`)
- pass-phrase a string of at most 63 characters (e.g. `<ra(<@2tAc<$`)

**Output** any reasonable output of the 64 hexadecimal digits

- e.g.
  `24343f69e98d3c08236a6db407584227cf2d1222b050e48f0cf25dee6563cd55`
- it is the result of the previous inputs

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so please make your program as short as possible!

Comment: Just to double check, is `24343f69e98d3c08236a6db407584227cf2d1222b050e48f0cf25dee6563cd55` the output of the inputs `stackexchange` and `<ra(<@2tAc<$`? And are we allowed to output bytes instead of hexadecimal digits?

Comment: @Okx Yes it is a complete example

Comment: Downvoted because output format is too strict.

Comment: Can you add a walk-through of how `stackexchange` and `<ra(<@2tAc<$` become `24343f69e98d3c08236a6db407584227cf2d1222b050e48f0cf25dee6563cd55`?

Comment: @Okx is it okay for you for a less restricted output?

Comment: @mdahmoune Output formats on challenges should generally be flexible, because adding bytes just to conform to the output format is annyoing

Comment: @Okx I edited the challenge

Comment: I like the challenge (from an infosec enthusiast's perspective) but I think it's too restrictive language-wise. Most golflangs just don't have a built-in SHA algorithm, so you'd have to implement that, to be able to create the HMAC function, and only then you'd be able to make a function to solve the challenge, which is both very convoluted and kinda misses the point of codegolfing.

Comment: @J.Salle how can make the challenge more accessible for other languages?

Comment: @J.Salle many golfing langs can't access the internet or read JSON easily, and yet we post [tag:stack-exchange-api] challenges, besides, I think implementing the algorithm is part of the fun, *and* having a challenge which golfing langs may not win is always refreshing...

Comment: I think it's a good challenge, so I'm not downvoting this challenge, but I'm not upvoting it, either. Ideally, challenges should be self-contained with no external links required. While it's very unlikely that the IETF will go away anytime soon, and I don't expect the entire algorithms to be spelled out here, some of the *explanation* from the RFCs could be migrated over to here to make the challenge even better.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork please feel free to edit the challenge...

Comment: @ close voters -- so, what makes this challenge "too broad"? Is it too broad for requiring "too much work" in languages that don't have PBKDF-2 in their standard libraries? I'd personally like to see a submission in such a language (or, maybe, provide one myself) :o

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform) lambda expression, <strike>88</strike> <strike>82</strike> 81 bytes

Takes input as byte arrays (curried, see comments), returns key as byte array.

```
p=>s=>new System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(p,s,4096).GetBytes(32);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFPTwIxEMXv@ykmGw@7ydIYNAayf6KgeNHEAMYD4VDLsDRAt@mUlY3hs69dNggePDTtvPw6b14rqCMKg/WOpMphUpHFbexdVmyKext7nuJbJM0FwpspcsO33rcHIDac6FcBaDQAstxKAWUhF/DKpQrIGtdxNgducgqPTEsCjHZKJJ@Vxdk8ujy3W5Yt01qnGaWZwq/TSBMUOyNtxYam0rbx1quKjZei2@v3HtHIEgfuOgU6ouj2un8Xsme0rXTTDeO6tS65Ae3m1yvDCSEFPzE8SO679kEkV37snTEiF8UBLplY416suMrxD7HGygHL4EmJYuHCsvfpqHe2PfuE4X9MYxKGp6bDQlGxQfbhkuKLVBgMpHViicaiYdNicnzUwBmHbIx64/4m8Dt@5PunJgevWYf6Bw)

Comment: @someone as I/O is relaxed, I have a complete new version operating on byte arrays ... updating.

Comment: You could just do `System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes` and save on the using-statement.

Comment: [82 bytes.](https://tio.run/##dZFBawIxEIXv@RXD0sMG1lBsKcqu0mprLy0U19KDeEjjuAY1u2Ti1qX427dZxVoPPYSQxzfz5k0UtVRusd6SNhmkFTncxOzvS0xw52LGjNwgFVIhvNk8s3LDvhmAWkuiXwWg0QDISacVlLmew6vUJiRnfcfpDKTNiB@YIwkw2hqVfFYOp7Po4uovenVYRMR7fYNfp2lSVFurXSWGtipcY1ssKzFeqHan23lEq0sc@HJqKqPb6@4dF8/ojtJNm8f10bWUFgo/erG0khB6ECRWhsl92z2o5CqI2Rkj8ik84EOpFe7UUpoML4gVVh5YhE9G5XOfU7xPRp2z7dmHR/AP05hwfmo6zA3laxQfPim@aIPhQDsvlmgdWjHJ08M@Q2/MxRiLtf@WMGgFURCcmuxZc/b1Dw "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Emigna thanks, that was kind of silly ;)

Comment: Use currying to save one more byte (`Func<byte[],Func<byte[],byte[]>> f = p=>s=>...`; call as `f(p)(s)`).

Comment: @someone is there some reference about the scoring rules for lambda expressions? I know currying and will happily use it, but think it's a bit silly to spend a lot more bytes for the type information -- is this information definitely not to be scored?

Comment: I didn't yet see anyone complaining about currying, so it should be okay.

Comment: currying is used and referenced in the tips section:https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85053/15214 (btw I use your answer as example)

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <s>192</s> 88 + 36 = 124 bytes

36 bytes for `import de.rtner.security.auth.spi.*;`

`a` is the SSID taken as a byte array, `b` is the password taken as a string. Outputs byte array. Requires [PBKDF2](https://github.com/m9aertner/PBKDF2/).

```
a->b->new PBKDF2Engine(new PBKDF2Parameters("HmacSHA1","UTF-8",a,4096)).deriveKey(b,32);
```

#### Old answer:

Takes SSID as char array and password as byte array. Outputs byte array.

```
a->b->{try{return javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1").generateSecret(new javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec(a,b,4096,256)).getEncoded();}catch(Exception e){return null;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFNi9swED0rv0KEFmRIRDa0C23S0KRN2LIUFnzoIeQgy5NEWVsy0ngbE/zb3VHtpV0dJPFm3nvzcVEvauoqsJf8uTNl5TzyC2GyRlPIY201GmflbvgsRlWdFUZzXagQ@E9lLL@N2AAGVEjPizM5LykkUvTGnvYHrvwpJJTJh/Oqt9Rn5feHyT8gaxAi0L@rFT/yL7xT01U2Xd3QNzcPWHv7t8ir1L6p0MkUNMGP0OyURucbeQL8Yakcq0GMnzaP33fzXwbPD6XS6cP6bpxQhgWvEHqqsPD7rWSoQMunzZZEU/oKNckmH2af7ifzj/dJpOPWapdDLpJFqxXqs9heNVSxCQ7Ja5m2LopF23aMLUaM9U1xD6EukPo6SlVVRSPiePazg0T3jeax9l41gkz@C94douWG@IEiUauf7aY2RQ6eh4zkYhNvYKqNRs7Y0XkuojnP@OfBPq6DMRayaAM2H5YlKbdUKMbvZ/PrmPYQ3UiijVfaBIRSuhplRckoiI2uJ/ZltaO265ZeieXXOa718l1HW9DPcKVF2xP8AQ)

Comment: Why do you need to catch the exception?

Comment: @someone `SecretKeyFactory#getInstance` throws `NoSuchAlgorithmException`

Comment: Does java require a try-catch for everything that throws exceptions?

Comment: @someone Yes, If it's declared in the method. Not always though, for example you can get a NullPointerException if you do something like `String s = null; s.isEmpty();` (which will throw a NPE) which doesn't need to be caught (but still can be), as in the `String#isEmpty` method declaration, it doesn't say it throws `NullPointerException`.