# Oops, I blew it up (with numbers)

Tags: code-golf, string

*Inspired by [There, I fixed it (with rope)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157600/there-i-fixed-it-with-rope), [There, I fixed it (with Tape)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157240/there-i-fixed-it-with-tape), [There, I broke it (with scissors)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157612/there-i-broke-it-with-scissors)*

Given a string with characters from `a-z` or `A-Z` (whichever you prefer), turn missing letters into numbers and make them explode.

---

## Example

Input: `abcafabc`

Output: `a12344321c`

***Why?***

1) Find the missing letters (only going forward in the alphabet): `abca(bcde)fabc`

2) Replace them with the number of missing letters: `abca4fabc`

3) Replace the number with

- Itself twice if it's even
- Itself + 1 if it's odd

In this case: `abca44fabc`

4) Explode those numbers outwards replacing any letters: `a12344321c`

---

## Challenge Rules

1. Explosions can't exceed the boundaries of the string

   - `ae -> 343` (3 letters are missing but since 3 is odd, it's been replaced by 4)
2. Numbers can be greater than 9

   - `az -> 23242423` (24 letters are missing and since 24 is even, it's repeated twice)
3. You can have multiple explosions

   - `abcefghijmnop -> ab121fghi1221nop`
4. Multiple explosions can overlap, take the sum of the number when they do

   - `abceghij -> abc(2)e(2)ghij -> ab12(1+1)21hij -> ab12221hij`
5. It's possible that no explosions occur, in that case simply return the string
6. No explosions between `ab`, `aa`, `aaa`, etc.
7. You are allowed to take the input in any reasonable format. Can be a single string, string-array/list, character-array/list, etc. Output has the same flexibility.
8. You are allowed to use lowercase and/or uppercase any way you'd like. This applies both to the input, output.

## General Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-golfing languages.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422).
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link to a test for your code, preferably [Tio](https://tio.run/#).
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

---

## Test cases:

```
Input  : 'abcdefgklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
Output : 'abcd1234321nopqrstuvwxyz'

Input  : 'abdefgjkl'
Output : 'a121ef1221kl'

Input  : 'xyzaz'
Output : '20212223242423'


Input  : 'abceghij'
Output : 'ab12221hij'

Input  : 'zrabc'
Output : 'zrabc'
```

Comment: I'm sorta confused on how to decide what the ground 0 is.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere : ground zero is the place where the missing letters should have been. Example: `abcefg` ground zero (represented by `HERE` would be `abcHEREefg`

Comment: But what about `acca`?

Comment: edit: why isn't it `1331` because both blanks explode?

Comment: Shouldn't it be 121ca?

Comment: This really would have been a lot more elegant without the even/odd rule. Though it could have been even messier if the explosions reflected at the start and end of the string :)

Comment: I think you should include an example where the grounds zero overlap such as `aeae -> 355553` (if that is correct)

Comment: Can my output be an array of chars and ints (eg. `['a','b',1,2,2,2,1,'h','i','j']` for example 1)?

Comment: Please work e.g. this example, that should clarify a lot  (overlap over multiple explosions with even steps) : `abcfghabceazabcazabcefghabcfabcd`

Comment: In case return array, `[a, z, a] => [23, 24, 24, 23]` or `[2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3]` botk okay?

Comment: @l4m2 `[23, 24, 24, 23]`

Comment: Are you out of these challenge ideas yet lol?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn, no not yet! I wanted to do a 2D version of if was better received!

Comment: Since output through function parameters is permitted as per the standard rules, may I assumed that such a parameter points to a “sufficiently“ large memory area to hold the (correct) result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), `-p` <s>110</s> 109 bytes

Handling the even/odd rules waste around 20 bytes

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s#.#$p+=$.;$c{$p-$_}+=$-=$z-abs$_+$z%2/2for-25..($z=ord($')-ord$&);$&x($.=$z<2||$z%2+2)#eg;s##$c{+pos}||$&#eg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3RjsIgEEXf@xUkjN02BDYh8any6m8YWrFbrQUBFVn99WWnTzPnZs5cZ/y8LSVQQcExBaKD4Rcch8MHiSvIXPcBDgzyRn7Lk/VcboVoICvrjw18tRwn1G0HdWpAoLCT7/d6zWRLzdgFSvElczZ8MK8xKt1mUA0aTvFVYQyWllCynxIJUUdDsIYsJkVikr662RTdD0dzGi/zdbHu5kO8P57plSvdr/H5MldIeuXBjD/Tucoe1@rPujjZJRTu/gE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 162 bytes

```ruby
->a{b=[*a=a.reduce{|x,y|[*x,*[(n=y.ord+~x[-1].ord)+n%2]*(n<1?0:2-n%2),y]}];i=-1;b.map{|x|d=-~i+=1;a.map!{|y|(z=x.to_i-(d-=1)*s=d<=>0)<1||x==b[i-s]?y:z+y.to_i}};a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7NboMwEITvfYr2UPFrK84xsMmDWFa1BhPID1ADrU1MXp3i9LI7881qtHqSdq1gJUd8SOAxAlKtyqlQD2dS63hs0piHLVja6TJ5Gk6Y8DJK2s@9iMM2Z6fdYU82F6VWLCJrgLBM0jv2W4UrgTybBFiGnnw8nHXhDIaO3VdDwpIAi@IByhyOuyhnzhkAyRsyiJM9zIl93S1Lhss6Ag9QFlhtI0gDVKj8kkWpqvP1dm@7/lsP4/Tza@z8Snxwud42vRH8Z4U6181lk7P2PeJtpAqL2r/aT@PwXnFDixr1IOIgWNY/)

Takes input as an array of chars, returns a mixed array of chars/ints. (I'm still not sure whether this is allowed after reading the comments to the original post. If not allowed, it's +3 bytes to fix).

### Explanation

First, we apply a `reduce` operation, where we aren't actually reducing anything, but rather reconstruct the array `a` as `[*x,*[...],y]`, where the middle part contains the numbers inserted at ground zero.

We also make a copy of the array: `b=[*a]` to serve as a reference, so that we don't get confused which numbers are at the center of the explosion, and which ones are introduced later on.

Then we iterate through `b` and for each element `x`, iterate through `a` to record, what effect `x` will have on each element `y` of `a`.

Conveniently, `to_i` method returns 0 for non-numeric chars, so that we don't have to worry about distinction between numbers and text.

In my initial code, arrays were indexed by `i` and `j`, but this was golfed down to use a "delta" value `d=i-j`.

Another helper variable is the sign of the delta: `s=d<=>0`. At the first occurrence it performs the same function as `abs`, and at the second - it helps us to block the other side of one-sided explosions as in `12344321`.

Ultimately, if `z` is estimated to be positive, we add it up with the integer equivalent of `y` and store in `a`, otherwise, `y` remains intact.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>351</s> 348 bytes

```python
Z=zip
R=range
E=lambda o:R(o,0,-1)
D=lambda d:[]if d<1else[[E(d),E(d+1)]]if d%2else[[E(d-1),[d]],[[],E(d)]]
def f(s):
	s=sum(([c]+D(ord(n)+~ord(c))for c,n in Z(s,s[1:]+' ')),[]);l=len(s);v=[0]*l
	for i,c in enumerate(s):
		if len(c)>1:
			for j,d in list(Z(R(i-1,-1,-1),c[0]))+list(Z(R(i,l),c[1])):v[j]+=d
	print(*(d or c for c,d in Z(s,v)),sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDBcsIgFDyHr@DSCRh0THuLjSf9AY8yHGIgSiSEQkyrh/56@ojTdoYB3u6@ZR/uPlx6@zZNx/KhHTqUvrJnhfalqbqTrHBfHEjP1myZU7T7BWXBhW6wfM@VCYrzPZGUwZblVMzEy@sfAY2MSyEY5yJqQIGkanBDAi1QEspw6wjhtch2pPeSWJp9x7OmtOk9rpnF2uIjCSzwvBBZilMKjoJuTGmUBZfNWPK1WBiUxAbN6tig7K1TvhrU85kEUkV1Tbd5LGdpy2SUGh0GciQHopc5mxdlNThSmv1TzEQwB7AYeSuyUqLEeW0HsiASx6D4GVf@xh0hZlCuTFM66c71fsDhHlBUhajpKkfC4FceNu1YJFdhkNrGvE/rwHCKl1ucAjs7MZhLRkeYFQabqlMNf3m@ms727gOcbuPn1/2BqlOE26tBUFWxrtX5olv08HD9AQ)

- −3 thanks to Kevin

The function `f` takes one string as input and prints the result to standard output.

### Ungolfed

```python
def range_downto_0(o):
    return range(o, 0, -1)

def D(d):
    return (
        []
        if d >= 0 else
        [[range_downto_0(d), range_downto_0(d + 1)]]
        if d % 2 else
        [[range_downto_0(d - 1), [d]], [[], range_downto_0(d)]]
    )

def f(s):
    s = sum(([c] + D(ord(n) + ord(c) - 1) for c, n in zip(s, s[1:] + ' ')), [])
    v = [0] * len(s)
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if len(c) == 2:
            for j, d in itertools.chain(
                zip(range(i - 1, -1, -1), c[0])),
                zip(range(i, len(s)), c[1])
            ):
                v[j] += d
    return ''.join(str(d) if d else c for c, d in zip(s, v))
```

### Explanation

1. Expand the string `s` to insert number range objects as placeholders for the "outward explosions". Save the result as a list `s`.
2. Create a list of zeros `v` with the same length as `s`.
3. Inspect `s` and, for every number range, add the numerical values to the value at their respective position in `v`. `v` now contains all the numbers that are going to be in the result at their correct positions.
4. Iterate over `s` and `v` simultaneously, take the entry from `v` if it is greater than 0 or the entry from `s` otherwise and print each chosen entry in order.

The expensive repeated array concatenation in step 1 is at best in O(n<sup>2</sup>) but could be expressed in O(n) using a generator (assuming Python can construct lists from generators in O(n)). The remainder of this algorithm is in O(n ⋅ min{n, |Σ|} ⋅ log |Σ|) with Σ being the alphabet or, if you want to regard Σ as a constant, straight out O(n) (assuming that Python can join string generators in O(n)). “min{n, |Σ|}” comes from the outward range expansion and “log |Σ|” results from the conversion of numbers to strings.

Comment: You can remove three spaces at `d<1else[[E(d)` (-2) and `d%2else` (-1).

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 395 bytes

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
f(char*s){char*S=s;while(*S++);const int l=S-s-1;int i=1,j=0,k,d,o,t[l*3],*v;for(;i<l;i++)(d=s[i]+~(t[j++]=s[i-1]))>0&&(t[j++]=-d,d%2||(t[j++]=0));l>0&&(t[j++]=s[l-1]);v=calloc(k=j,4);for(i=0;i<k;i++){if((d=-t[i])>0){d+=o=d%2;for(j=0;j<d&&j<=i;j++)v[i-j]+=d-j;i+=!o;for(j=o;j<d&&i+j<k;j++)v[i+j]+=d-j;}}for(i=0;i<k;i++){d=v[i];printf(d?"%d":"%c",d?d:t[i]);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBPc9sgEMXP1qegytgBgTp225MRyTmnHnxUdVDAskFEuAIrfxz3q6uLas94pif2Lb99b2dlvpNyHO90J@1RbQsflNXPX/cPyW1Lu9hpsNzXfebJaXo3wvPXvbZbnG0oJVy6zgeku4Cs2OQ@X/FYa7FiRixZyxRzLJQ2@16xbOCN6zHXheUaZrESvtQV/YNDaSitospXFSEPy8Xi2ssVU/Nvn59XvSSE21vAlzYO8UHI2loncSsM@0GmKC2WkNZOaSfdYEjMA0RCAjkpKpwA74mEZbkp1GJhCqE5GJMBljEVFSo3MC@@uAvn/nGaGjC@gPQKns//xSoBQMUPPdylweoxnat0nc5lytSjWk/bwNgYr/ZS6w7Hou53kqF4b5RBPZQVSU7JDLzR9K@RQCsOTzGhUEFSMgNkdslJn7rDMSC0Rvdzf/@r@3kMUYNMGZosYy7wDb5VwHicAp9GeU7O41g/S7Vtdq196dzhd@/DcXh9e/@Afmyb1o6g6qjldrfXZvzoofwL)

`f` takes input as a null-terminated character array and returns its result on standard output.

### Explanation

This is my first C submission to Code Golf. The algorithm is the same as in my [Python submission](/a/158179/68800).