# Numbers Manipulation challenge

Tags: code-golf, random

Use any programming language to generate two random digits between 1 and 9 (including both). Then your program should display:

- in the first line: the first random digit,
- in the second line: the second random digit,
- in the third line: a number whose tens and units digits are the first and second random digits respectively,
- in the fourth line: the number from the third line raised to the power of 2.

For example, if digits "9" and "2" were generated, your program should display exactly:

```
9
2
92
8464
```

Comment: Can we output an array?

Comment: Can we sample without replacement, ie exclude 1,1 2,2 3,3... from the pairs?

Comment: (i.e., what's the distribution of the random numbers?)

Comment: You should probably specify that the digits are pairwise independent and uniformly random. Otherwise, one can go with a degenerate distribution and write "cat (10 Bytes): 1[newline]1[newline]11[newline]121"

Comment: @YonatanN The standard assumption on PPCGcfor the term `random` is that all possibilities have a non-zero chance of occuring.

Comment: Why did you accept my answer just yet, when there are two 9-byte solutions that are shorter? For code-golf challenges you should accept the shortest one (and sometimes the earliest edit/post if there are more than one shortest), or don't accept an answer at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>14</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2F9LΩ=}J=n,
```

-3 bytes thanks to *@Emigna*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyM3S59xK21ov2zyd//8B)

**Explanation:**

```python
2F    }        # Loop 2 times:
  9LΩ          #  Create a list in the range [1,9], and pick a random element from it
     =         #  Output it (without popping it from the stack)
       J       # Join them together
        =      # Output it (without popping it from the stack)
         n     # Take it to the power of 2
          ,    # And output it as well
```

---

**11 bytes alternative:**

```
9LãΩ©`®JDn»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0ufw4nMrD61MOLTOyyXv0O7//wE)

**Explanation:**

```python
9L             # List in the range [1,9]
  ã            # Cartesian product with itself: [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],...,[9,7],[9,8],[9,9]]
   Ω           # Take a random element from it
    ©          # Store it in the register (without popping)
     `         # Pop and push both items as separated items onto the stack
      ®        # Retrieve the list of digits from the register again
       J       # Join them together to a single 2-digit number
        Dn     # Duplicate it, and take the power of 2 of the copy
          »    # Merge all values on the stack by newlines (and output implicitly)
```

Comment: Shorter in a looP: `2F9LΩ=}J=n,`

Comment: @Emigna I was about to look for shorter alternatives, but smart use of the `=`!

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>48</s> 47 bytes

```r
cat(x<-sample(9,2,T),y<-x%*%c(10,1),y^2,fill=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKPCRrc4MbcgJ1XDUsdIJ0RTp9JGt0JVSzVZw9BAxxDIjTPSScvMybE11Pz/HwA)

Thanks to J.Doe for golfing down a byte.

Comment: Tweak to `cat` args. [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKPCRrc4MbcgJ1XDUsdIJ0RTp9JGt0JVSzVZw9BAxxDIjTPSScvMybE11Pz/HwA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @J.Doe thanks! Probably there are other submissions where `fill` would be handy...

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

*-1 Byte from @Oliver*

```
2ÆÒ9ö
pU¬Uì ²
```

---

```
2ÆÒ9ö
pU¬Uì ²     Full program
-----------------------------------------
2Æ            Range [0,2) and map 
   9ö         Random number in range [0, 9)
  Ò           increased by 1
              This result is assigned to U

p            Push into U    
 U¬          Elements in U joined
   Uì ²      and elements joined squared
             Implicit output each element 
             separated with new line -R
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=MsbSOfYKcFWsVewgsg==&input=LVI=)

Comment: You can use `2ÆÒ9ö` to save a byte on the first line.

Answer (score 5):

## Vim, 43 bytes

```
:%!$RANDOM

:s/0//g
2f:y2hVpo<C-r>=<C-r>0*<C-r>0
<Esc>kYPa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/30pVUSXI0c/F35eLy6pY30BfP53LKM2q0igjrCBfyFbIQEvIgEs6OzIgkev/fwA)

Not the right tool for the job. This produces *most likely* the desired output

Step by step:

- `:%!$RANDOM` <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  Produces a string like `/bin/bash: 25266: command not found`
- `:s/0//g`
  removes all zeroes
- `2f:y2hVp`
  moves the cursor to the colon after the number, copy the last two digits and replace the entire string with those
- `o` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `=` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `0*` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `0` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  add a new line and evaluate an expression. In this case, I'll multiply the number in register 0 (the one that was just copied) with itself.
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> `kYPa` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  Copy the upper line and paste it above. The cursor ends up in the first line, on the first character. Now we just have to append a line break to it

Limitations: If the result of `$RANDOM` is a number with less than two non-zero digits, this will not produce the desired output

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>68</s> 67 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to cleblanc*

```c
f(r){r=rand()%81*10/9+11;printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d",r/10,r%10,r,r*r);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9No0izusi2KDEvRUNT1cJQy9BA31Lb0NC6oCgzryRNQ0k1JSYPgZV0ivQNDXSKVEGETpFWkaZ17X@gQoXcxMw8DU2Fai7OYrBZJZm5qRoGmprWXJxpGiCyKLWktChPwcCaq/Y/AA)

Comment: save one byte using `r;f()` --> `f(r)`

Answer (score 4):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 28 bytes

```
t:2?10;t,:10/t;$t,:t[2]*t[2]
```

**Explanation**

```
t:2?10                       //define t as two random numbers from 1-10
       t,:10/t               //join the base 10 joining of the elements of t to t
                 t,:t[2]*t[2]//join the square of the index 2 element to t
               $            //String each element of the result (to output on newlines)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v8TKyN7QwLpEx8rQQL/EWgXIKIk2itUCEf//AwA)

**Cleaner Output, 32 bytes**

```
t:2?10;t,:10/t;`0:$t,:t[2]*t[2];

               `0:               //Cleanly prints the strings
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v8TKyN7QwLpEx8rQQL/EOsHASgXILok2itUCEdb//wMA)

Comment: If we're allow to return an array then `a,b,b*b:10/a:1+2?9` for **18 chars** [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P1EnSSdJK8nK0EA/0cpQ28je8v9/AA "K (oK) – Try It Online")

Comment: +1 Much neater, its only the extra $ character to match the output of my first answer, with -9 bytes. I hadn't tried to fit it into one expression

Comment: `2?10` could generate a 0. the challenge requires 1-9.

Comment: [`\`0:$a,*\2#10/a:1+2?9;`](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P8HASiVRRyvGSNnQQD/RylDbyN7S@v9/AA) (works [in ngn/k](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/BwEolUUcrxkjZ0EA/0cpQ28je0vr/fwA) too)

Comment: That works great in ok, the issue with it in ngn/k is that it seems to generate the same output on every run

Comment: @Thaufeki the random seed in ngn/k predetermined, like in the original k

Comment: oh ok cool, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>83</s> 76 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to nwellnhof.

```python
from random import*
k=randint(9,89)*10//9+1
[*map(print,[k//10,k%10,k,k*k])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocWXbggQy80o0LHUsLDW1DA309S21DbmitXITCzQKioAyOtHZ@vqGBjrZqiBCJ1srO1Yz9v9/AA)

Comment: [82 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRXZggQy80q4Em2LNAx1LDW5kmCMbNtELUMD7SSuaK3cxAKNgiKgMp3oRJ0knWydbK3sWM3Y//8B "Python 3 – Try It Online").

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 39 bytes

```perl6
{.comb,$_,$_²}([~] roll 1..9: 2)>>.put
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/79aLzk/N0lHJR6IDm2q1Yiui1Uoys/JUTDU07O0UjDStLPTKygt@f8fAA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 67 bytes

```javascript
f=_=>(n=Math.random()*90+10|0)%10?(n/10|0)+`
${n%10}
${n}
`+n*n:f()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYhJDkAwFED3zkHyq1G1JCkncAZtzML/UmKDs9ewesNkDrPVdlz3CKlpnetUpXJAVZp9ENZgQwuwMJU8kZdkQSILwPh3rj3/xPfcH29Pcwwx64C5mnCjuRUz9fA2cw8)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>48</s> 45 bytes

```powershell
($a,$b=1..9*2|Random -c 2)
($x="$a$b")
+$x*$x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0MlUUclydZQT89Sy6gmKDEvJT9XQTdZwUiTS0OlwlZJJVElSUmTS1ulQkul4v9/AA)

Concatenates two ranges `1..9` together, pipes that to `Get-Random` with a `-c`ount of `2` to pull out two elements, stores them into `$a` and `$b`, and encapsulates that in parens to place a copy of them on the pipeline.

Next we string concatenate `$a$b` and store it into `$x`, again placing in parens to put a copy on the pipeline. Finally we take `$x` squared and leave it on the pipeline.

All the results are gathered from the pipeline and an implicit `Write-Output` gives us newlines between elements for free.

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to mazzy.*

Comment: Smart get-random

Comment: I think `1..9|Random -c 2` completely satisfies the condition `two random digits between 1 and 9 (including both)`

Comment: ...if not, then `1..9*2` is shorter

Comment: @mazzy Other answers seem to pick the two digits with replacement, so I did so as well. Thanks for the `1..9*2` golf!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
9ṗ2XṄ€ḌṄ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/y4c7pRhEPd7Y8alrzcEcPkHFo0///AA)

#### How it works

```
9ṗ2XṄ€ḌṄ²  Main link. No arguments.

9          Set the return value to 9.
 ṗ2        Promote 9 to [1, ..., 9] and take the second Cartesian power, yielding
           [[1, 1], [1, 2], ..., [9, 8], [9, 9]].
   X       Pseudo-randomly select one of the pairs.
    Ṅ€     Print each integer in the pair, followed by a newline.
      Ḍ    Undecimal; convert the integer pair from base 10 to an integer.
       Ṅ   Print the integer, followed by a newline.
        ²  Take the square.
           (implicit) Print the last return value.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
^
i,
hO9
hO9T2
```

Note that the newlines are significant. Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%5E%0Ai%2C%0AhO9%0AhO9T2&debug=0).

Explanation, with newlines replaced with ¶ character:

```
^¶i,¶hO9¶hO9T2   Implicit: T=10

      O9         Choose a random number in [0-9)
     h           Increment
    ¶            Output with newline - value printed is yielded as expression result
        ¶hO9     Do the above again
   ,             Wrap the two previous results in a two-element array
  i         T    Convert to decimal from base 10
 ¶               Output with newline
^            2   Square the previous result, implicit print
```

Comment: @Downvoter - any particular reason why?

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```ruby
puts [(a=11+10*rand(81)/9)/10,a%10,a,a*a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFghWiPR1tBQ29BAqygxL0XDwlBT31JT39BAJ1EVROgkaiXG/v8PAA)

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL, <strike>142</strike> <strike>105</strike> <strike>115</strike> <strike>114</strike> <strike>96</strike> 78 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ int=RAND()*9+1,@a int=RAND()*9+1SELECT @,@a,10*@+@a,POWER(10*@+@a,2)
```

*-37 bytes: Realized I could just use two different random numbers and use the first digits from each!*
*+10 bytes: Edited to meet requirements of range from 1-9, instead of 0-9*
*-1 byte: Changed RIGHT() to LEFT() in @b*
*-18 bytes: Various changes suggested by [BradC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/175006/numbers-manipulation-challenge/175026#comment421745_175026)*
*-18 bytes: More changes suggested by [BradC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/175006/numbers-manipulation-challenge/175026?noredirect=1#comment421762_175026)*

Ungolfed:

```sql
-- Setting RAND() separately in these produces different numbers.
-- [RAND() * b + a] sets the range for a random number, from a to b inclusive.
-- Declaring as an int removes the numbers after the decimal.
DECLARE @ int = RAND() * 9 + 1,
        @a int = RAND() * 9 + 1

SELECT @,                       -- first random digit
       @a,                      -- second random digit
       10 * @ + @a,             -- multiply first digit by ten, and add second
       POWER(10 * @ + @a, 2)    -- third digit squared
```

Comment: The stuff in the first comment definitely works, I'll edit that in. Problem with making the variables `int`s is that I would need to cast each individually as `char`s in the `SELECT` where necessary. With that, since each variable would need to be converted twice (in `@+@a` and `POWER(@+@a,2)`), it'd add more characters than it would save.

Comment: Good calls, thanks. Don't know why I didn't think of multiplying the first number by ten...

Comment: No problem, I'll delete my comments since you've incorporated them.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>84</s> 75 bytes

```python
from random import*
k=randint(9,89)*10/9+1
for x in k/10,k%10,k,k*k:print x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocWXbggQy80o0LHUsLDW1DA30LbUNudLyixQqFDLzFLL1DQ10slVBhE62VrZVQRFQrULF//8A)

---

Saved

- -1 bytes, thanks to Erik the Outgolfer
- -8 bytes, thanks to nwellnhof

Comment: Moderate golf: [83 bytes](https://tio.run/##Dco7DoAgEADRnlNsCbgFUJpwGEBQEvlkpdDTI9UUb/o3rlbNnIlaAXL1WMmlNxqSOfT2caXfkS85I9eolZAGjWDBOqnV5llqBC/kCuvGgEGGvVOuA945fw).

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>99</s> <s>98</s> <s>90</s> <s>81</s> 80 bytes

```java
v->{int i=81;i*=Math.random();return(i=i*10/9+11)/10+"\n"+i%10+"\n"+i+"\n"+i*i;}
```

-8 bytes after being inspired by [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175015/52210).
-9 bytes thanks to *@nwellnhof*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PY7BisJADIbvPkUQhJkWW@emDN03sBdhL7qH7LRq3Gkq07SwSJ@9O2WLlyR/Qvi@Bw64fVQ/k/PYdXBE4tcKgFjqcEVXQzlHgJME4hs49dlSBYO2cTuuYukEhRyUwFDANGw/XvEXqNgbS0lxRLlnAblqG6VtqKUPrKigxOzyQ2qMzs0uXV94ndLmPS0tITtOdmY8@28fGQtqmA2aKKr@pc5fgHqx/O2kbrK2l@wZT@JZceYU997rRXmc/gA)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->{                        // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  int i=81;i*=Math.random();//  Create a random integer `i` in the range [0,81)
  return(i=i*10/9+11)       //  Set `i` to 10 times `i`, integer-divided by 9, and 11 added
        /10+"\n"            //  Return the first digit of `i`, a newline,
        +i%10+"\n"          //         the last digit of `i`, a newline,
        +i+"\n"             //         `i` itself, a newline,
        +i*i;}              //         and `i` multiplied by itself
                            //         All concatted to each other
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
≔⭆²⊕‽⁹θ↓θθ⸿ＩＸＩθ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU8juKQoMy/dN7FAw0hHwTMvuSg1NzWvJDVFIygxLyU/V8NSU1NTR6FQ05orAKiwRMPKJb88D1kAwVKKKVKCc5wTi0s0AvLLU4sgzEKgKUZAs6z///@vW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⭆²⊕‽⁹θ
```

Generate two random characters in the range `1` to `9`.

```
↓θ
```

Output them downwards i.e. on separate lines.

```
θ⸿
```

Output them horizontally on their own line.

```
ＩＸＩθ²
```

Cast to integer, square, cast back to string for implicit print.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>130</strike> <strike>129</strike> <strike>109</strike> 98 bytes

```cs
var r=new Random();int a=r.Next(1,10),b=r.Next(1,10),c=a*10+b;Console.Write($"{a} {b} {c} {c*c}");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcexDsIgEADQX7k0DlBrU2bCYDrroIPz9UoMSQsJh1VD@HbU0eENj/hAIdr6YOfvcH1zsqsGWpAZjpCBEyZHsAU3wwmdFxJy3TBCNN4@4YJ@DquQ2vkEaGJ/tq8kVKcG2U3/JYOtGvaTHoPnsNj@Fl2yYtdkLJCnL/ppqTRS11LqBw)

*-1 byte: edited console output to use wildcards (thanks to [Logern](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36046/logern))*
*-20 bytes: changed* `r` *to* `var` *from* `Random`*, changed format of* `c`*; fixed* `r.Next()` *operators (thanks to [LiefdeWen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68917/liefdewen))*
*-11 bytes: changed format of* `c` *(thanks to [user51497](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/82625/user51497))*

Ungolfed:

```cs
var r = new Random();                   // initializes random number generator
int a = r.Next(1, 10),                  // gets random number between 1 and 9 inclusive
    b = r.Next(1, 10),                  // gets random number between 1 and 9 inclusive
    c = a * 10 + b;                     // concatenates a and b into one two-digit number
Console.Write($"{a} {b} {c} {c*c}");    // writes a, b, c, and c^2 to the console
```

Comment: [129 bytes-Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc09C8IwFIXhv3IpDonW4Cqhg3RWxArOt2mQQJtA7vWLkN8eKy46vMMDB46htQnRlhs5f4XuRWwnDWZEIthBAmJkZ@Ae3AB7dF5ISOWEfggTxMbbB3whpHaeAZuoDvbJYlNvZd3/yTTzQh0xkhWozqHjOH8Kuep/IHUbPIXRqkt0bMWiSpgh9XPm09LkSuqSc3kD "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Comment: [109 bytes](https://tio.run/##VcqxCsIwEIDhVzmCQ2JrqHPoIM6K6OB8TQ8JtAnkYlVCnj3W0eEbfvgt72yIVJ/s/ANuH040G7ATMsMBMnDC5CwswY1wQuelglwXjBB7Ty@4oh/DLJVxPgH2UZ/pnWTX7jvVDv9p@/XRF4xMEhshmkGZY/AcJtL36BLJjchYIA8r@7O1RShTS6lf) Also your `.Next` needs to include 10 so it can random 9

Comment: @LiefdeWen Thanks. Didn't realize the max value of `Random.Next()` was exclusive. The min value is inclusive, though, so that needs to stay at 1 to fit the requirement of being between 1-9 inclusive.

Comment: [-11 bytes](https://tio.run/##VcexDsIgEADQX7k0DlBrU2bCYDrroIPz9UoMSQsJh1VD@HbU0eENj/hAIdr6YOfvcH1zsqsGWpAZjpCBEyZHsAU3wwmdFxJy3TBCNN4@4YJ@DquQ2vkEaGJ/tq8kVKcG2U3/JYOtGvaTHoPnsNj@Fl2yYtdkLJCnL/ppqTRS11LqBw) `c = a*10 + b;`

Comment: This looks to be a snippet rather than [a full function or program](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/42963). Here is [the guide to C#](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11927/42963) that should be able to help you turn your snippet into an acceptable answer.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork In reality, we're golfing against the language, and not against others, as C# cannot compete. There is a minimum number of required characters to create a C# program. See [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/287/83280).

Comment: @Meerkat The entire program is not required, but you do need it to be in a function. That actually *saves* bytes then, because you can return rather than `Console.Write` ing

Comment: [94 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY2xCsIwFABn8xWP4pDUWto5piCCmw46OKdpKoE2gSStlZBvj3VwcLjh4OCE2wtjZZqc0k@4v52XIwUxcOfgCAGQ89wrAedJi4PSvgDn7Zo20LO0sCbM3IJlWr7gxnVnRkzomgFntrzKxeO6qCtStP8qGM/ratdSK/1k9TYLPEJoV8SXXMSMxkTR7z4b1cGFK40JBLQ5Ge3MIMuHVV7iHleEUBRRTB8 "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online") and a valid lambda function answer. (x is an unused input to save 1 byte, which is allowed as per PPCG standard rules)

Comment: If you use the Visual C# Interactive Compiler (csi), [you don't need the boilerplate](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P@/LLFIocg2L7VcISgxLyU/V0PTOjOvRCHRtkjPL7WiRMNQx9BAUycJlZtsm6hlaKCdZO2cn1ecn5OqF16UWZKqoaJUnVirUJ0ExMkgrJVcq6Rp/f8/AA "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online"). You'll have to replace the spaces in the output with newlines though. The challenge is rather specific about that.

Comment: Also by using `Console.Write` in the program I believe you also need to include the byte count of `using System;`, in which case it'd be shorter to specify `System.Console.Write`

Comment: [97 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY69CsIwGABn8xQf4pDUKu0cUxDBTQcdXFzSNJVA@wWS1B9Cnr1WwcHl4OCGU36lrNPj4A3e4PzyQfccVCe9hy1EID7IYBTsB1QbgyEHH9yUVtCK8SmqeJcOnED9gJPExvaU8SkDKdz6qJ@BlnlZsLz@VyVkVhbLmjsdBoeLeZTpirH@QH2RqTTnaeTkN3C3poGDNEgZRDLbWfS20@uLM0HTlhaMcZJIGt8 "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online") with newlines

Comment: Btw, csi lets you use `Write` instead of `System.Console.Write` and you don't need the trailing semicolon. [92 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P@/LLFIocg2L7VcISgxLyU/V0PTOjOvRCHRtkjPL7WiRMNQx9BAUycJlZtsm6hlaKCdZB1elFmSqqGiVJ1YG5NXnQQiksGEVnKtkub//wA "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 27 bytes

```
11+int(89rand
Disp iPart(.1Ans),10fPart(.1Ans),Ans,Ans²
```

(can generate a 0 in the 2nd random number)

Uses kamoroso94's Disp layout, but makes use of TI-BASIC integer compression.  Generating the 2 random integers as a single compressed integer and extracting them via iPart and fPart allows for shaving several bytes.  It's possible to generate the random integers seperately in the same number of bytes by creating them simultaneously in a list:

```
1+int(9rand(2
```

But the repeated calls to the list via Ans(1) and Ans(2) end up taking many more bytes than the integer compression technique.  It's also important to note that rand is generally advisable over randInt( for random integer generation as they either use equivalent bytes, or rand will be shorter when the lower bound is 0, and rand has the added flexibility of list generation.

Comment: This doesn't work; sometimes it generates 0 for the second digit.

Comment: Yeah I see what I missed now, I don't think it's possible to improve from the 31 bytes and avoid the zeros then without messing with the output formatting.  You can get 33 bytes by adding 2 randInt() and extracting them as shown here or 33 bytes again via the random list.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 64 bytes

```php
<?$d=($c=(10*($a=rand(1,9))+$b=rand(1,9)))*$c;echo"$a
$b
$c
$d";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxl4lxVZDJdlWw9BAS0Ml0bYoMS9Fw1DHUlNTWyUJiaeppZJsnZqcka@kksilksSlksylkqJk/f//v/yCksz8vOL/unkA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 43 bytes

```
100*
L$`
$.`
A`0
G?`..
\*\L`.
..
$.($&*$&*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8vQwECLy0clgUtFL4HLMcGAy90@QU@PK0YrxidBjwvIUtHTUFHTAqL//wE) Explanation:

```
100*
L$`
$.`
```

Count from 0 to 99.

```
A`0
```

Delete multiples of 10.

```
G?`..
```

Pick a random 2-digit number.

```
*\L`.
```

Output the digits separately.

```
\
```

Output the number.

```
..
$.($&*$&*
```

Square and implicitly output the number.

Answer (score 0):

### [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), <s>100</s> 86 bytes

```
1 DEF FNR(X)=INT(RND*X)+1:A=FNR(9):B=FNR(9):PRINT A:PRINT B:C=A*10+B:PRINT C:PRINT C^2
```

**Output**

```
5
8
58
3364
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, 31 bytes

```
randInt(1,9→A
randInt(1,9→B
10A+B
Disp A,B,Ans,Ans²
```

Answer (score 0):

## [sfk](http://stahlworks.com/dev/swiss-file-knife.html), 99 bytes

```
rand 1 9 +setvar a +rand 1 9 +setvar b +tell -var "#(a)
#(b)
#(a)#(b)" +calc -var #(a)#(b)*#(a)#(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K07L/v@/KDEvRcFQwVJBuzi1pCyxSCFRQRtDLElBuyQ1J0dBF8RRUtZI1ORS1kgCEYmaIIaSgnZyYk4yRB4mqAVj/P8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## perl -E, 45 bytes

```
$_=10+int rand 90;y/0/1/;say for/./g,$_,$_**2
```

This exploits the lack of a requirement that all random numbers should be picked with equal probability (it will pick numbers ending in 1 twice as often as ending in any other digit).

Answer (score 0):

### Visual C#, <s>102 Bytes</s>; 101 bytes

+2 Upper bound of Random.Next() exclusive, 10 instead of 9 
-3 Thanks to [LiefdeWen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68917/liefdewen) (var instead of Random)

```
var r=new Random();int x=r.Next(1,10),y=r.Next(1,10),z=x*10+y;Console.Write($"{x}\n{y}\n{z}\n{z*z}");
```

normal form:

```
var r = new Random();
int x = r.Next(1, 10), 
    y = r.Next(1, 10), 
    z = x * 10 + y;
Console.Write($"{x}\n{y}\n{z}\n{z * z}");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vcq9CsIwFEDh2T7FpTgktZZ2Dp2cFdHBQR1CDCXQJpAba9KQZ48/m8sHB47ArUCRn6j0AOeATk6sECNHhKM1g@VTLFbouFMCZqMesOdKE3T281/vwO2ANOaZW7C9li84cf0wE6FMaQe@t81Beke6umtpHf5z6X3VtZvAdkajGWVzscpJsi6jTzcdw5flR7WkkrKcUn4D)

### Visual C#, <s>85 bytes 89 bytes</s> 91 Bytes

+4 bytes: fixed problem with 0 as second digits, borrowing the `*10/9+1` from other answers

+2 bytes: preventing numbers <11

Even shorter solution

```
var r=new Random();int x=r.Next(9,89)*10/9+1;Console.Write($"{x/10}\n{x%10}\n{x}\n{x*x}");
```

normal form:

```
var r = new Random();
int x = r.Next(9, 89)*10/9+1;
Console.Write($"{x/10}\n{x%10}\n{x}\n{x*x}");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYu9CsIwFEZ3n@JSFJKq/dksoZOzIjo4qENIQwm0CeTGGgl59lqLeIbzLecTuBUoxicq3cLljU72bCE6jggna1rL@wVMhNlf0HGnBAxGNXDgShN0dvreHsBti/TfhREGbsHWWr7gzHVjekKZ0g58bbOj9I5Um11F07LIq3XJ9kaj6WR2tcpJskyCz8si3nXwq9/OSn1MKBtjHD8)

Comment: [98 bytes](https://tio.run/##VcqxCsIwFEDR2X7FozgktZZ2Dp2cFdHBQRxCGkqgTSAv1qQh3x7r6HCGC1fgUaDIb1R6hHtAJ2dWiIkjwtWa0fI5Fjt03CkBi1EDnLnSBJ3d/ucLuB2RxrxwC7bX8gM3rgczE8qUduB721ykd6Sru5bW4T/X3lddewjsZDSaSTYPq5wk@zL6BDFs1p9qTSVlOaX8BQ). You also had to include 10 in `.Next` to make 9 possible

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 69 bytes

```
prin reduce[x: random 9 n:"^/"y: random 9 n z: do rejoin[x y]n z * z]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcqxCoAgFAXQva@4OLY452e0ikH03mDgM6xI/XkTWloPJzG1mcm6Ia1CMeiTmSDx0ZcP3I7kBYnp3thmg@9gghi1aFX@gmpAsec9erEZxXXCiOpaewE)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 9 bytes

```
2æ8w)o§o²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/ocKdlef6h5fmHNv3/DwA)

### Explanation

For the example, the first random integer is 4, the second is 7.

```
2æ         Start for-loop of length two, with the next 3 chars as the body
  8w       Random non-negative integer less than or equal to 8
    )      Increment by 1
     o     Output without popping (stack is unchanged)
           For loop ends, stack is now [4, 7], the first two lines have been printed
     §     Concatenate the two numbers on the stack (stack is [47])
      o    Output without popping (stack is unchanged)
       ²   Square number and output implicitly
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 95 bytes

```
@set/at=%random%%%9+1,u=%random%%%9+1,n=t*10+u,p=n*n
@for %%a in (%t% %u% %n% %p%)do @echo %%a
```

`%random%` isn't a real variable, it's interpolated at parse time, so you need the `%`s even inside `set/a`. (Also don't try using it in a loop!)