# Injection from two strings to one string

Tags: code-golf, string, open-ended-function

### Challenge

Write a program that applies an injective function which takes an ordered pair of strings as input and one string as output. In other words, each input must map to a unique output.

### Specifics

- The input may be *any* two strings of arbitrary length, but will consist only of printable ASCII characters (codes \$[32, 126]\$).
- Similarly, the output string has no length restriction, but it must consist only of printable ASCII characters.
- If your language can't handle arbitrary-length strings, the program may merely work *theoretically* for strings of any size.
- The mapping from inputs to outputs should be consistent between executions of the program. Otherwise, the mapping you use is completely up to you, as long as it is an injection.
- The input is ordered. If the two input strings are different, they should produce a different output than if they were swapped. \$s \neq t \implies f(s, t) \neq f(t, s)\$
- Not every string needs to be a possible output.
- The shortest answer in each language wins!

### Test cases

The following inputs should all result in different outputs. To avoid confusion, strings are surrounded by guillemets («») and separated by single spaces.

```
«hello» «world»
«lelho» «drowl»
«diffe» «_rent»
«notth» «esame»

«Code» «Golf»
«Co» «deGolf»
«CodeGolf» «»

«» «»
«» « »
« » «»
« » «  »
«  » « »

«abc", » «def»
«abc» «, "def»
«abc' » «'def»
«abc'» « 'def»

«\» «"»
«\\» «\"»
```

Comment: Hmm I just noticed "Write a program that..." - note that by meta consensus (currently 46 up, 1 down) ["Restricting to just programs requires explicitly specifying "full program" rather than just "program""](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6912/53748). I hope you did not mean to try to restrict this, but if you did you'll need to update the post accordingly and address those of us which have already submitted functions as answers.

Comment: If our language can only take input from STDIN may we choose to reserve one printable character as our string separator?

Comment: I do wish I had noticed that "stringify" works as a solution while this was in the sandbox, as it does seem to make the challenge a bit worse. I still think this is a good challenge for languages that don't really have string support.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I feel bad -- I noticed a weaker string-representation idea in the Sandbox, but hadn't thought through how short and general it can be.

Comment: @xnor Don't worry too much, after all I missed it too! But I guess the lesson is to explain algorithms in the sandbox even if they feel like they might not be great. This is definitely the kind of problem that can always slip though, though, so I'm not sure even if you had that anyone would've noticed before it got posted here.

Comment: @JonathanAllan The intent was to allow functions.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Using a printable character separator is fine in that case, as long as it isn't chosen specifically to make handling the input strings easier.

Comment: Can either of the strings be empty?

Comment: @Shaggy Yes, either or both can.

Comment: Can we have some test cases? Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

### brainfuck, <s>30</s> <s>29</s> <s>27</s> 23 bytes

```
,[-[+.>]-[>+<---]>.-.,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ1o3WlvPLlY32k7bRldXN9ZOT1dPJ/b//7T8fMakxCIA)

Inputs are separated by a `0x01` byte.

This turns `["foo", "bar"]` into `fUToUToUTUTbUTaUTrUT`. To recover the original two strings, take groups of 3 characters, find the one where the second letter isn't `U`, and split there.

Comment: @Grimy Sorry, misunderstood "Inputs are separated by a 0x01 byte."

Answer (score 17):

## JavaScript (ES6), 14 bytes

Takes input as an array of 2 strings. Inspired by [Luis' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193645/58563).

```javascript
JSON.stringify
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@98r2N9Pr7ikKDMvPTOt8n9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaaRrRSRmpOTr6SjoJSeX5RTopSrKYmF7qSRJB0UjIOyaRkkDRY8j8A)

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>21</s>  20 bytes

Takes input as `(a)(b)`.

```javascript
a=>b=>[a.length,a]+b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcq7DYAgEADQ3jGoICobwCLG4vhrLpwBouNjaI31eyfcUG05rrZmcr4H1UFpo/QGEn2OLS2wz6ZbypXQS6TIA2fJIxITnD1U0DEhpk@Agcb@krEDB/UX)

Returns the length of \$a\$, followed by a comma, followed by the concatenation of \$a\$ and \$b\$.

Comment: Goddamnit! Was just about to use the `stringify` trick myself!

Comment: Breaks with `a="hello",""` `b="world"` and `a="hello"` `b="","world"`

Comment: @Soleil That would give `["\"hello\",\"\"","\"world\""]` and `["\"hello\"","\"\",\"world\""]`.

Comment: @Arnauld the backslash protection won't be visible. The function won't inject.

Comment: @Soleil I don't understand what you mean. `JSON.stringify()` definitely escapes `"`. [See a hex dump](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP13DqTQtLbVIwyvY30@vuKQoMy89M61SQ11JXVNT8/9/AA).

Answer (score 15):

### jq -c, 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8DwTRSmn5@Uo6CkpJiUVKsf/yC0oy8/OK/@smAwA)

This definitely feels like cheating...? But it seems to comply with the rules of the challenge.

By default, `jq` will output its input in a human-readable JSON format. The `-c` (compact) flag tells `jq` to output in "compact" style, which removes the newlines (since the challenge forbids non-printable ASCII).

Comment: OP allows empty input, so wouldn't a="", b="x" give same output as a="x" b=""

Comment: @Gnudiff How so? They would give `["","x"]` and `["x",""]` respectively

Comment: Sorry, you're right.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 3 bytes

```python
str
```

A (built-in) function which, given a list of the two strings, gives a string representation of the list

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzv7ik6H9BUWZeiUaaRrRSWn6@ko5SUmKRerFSrKbmfwA)**

Comment: More pithy than Pyth...

Comment: Well, the 1 byte Pyth solution ` does the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I *still* feel I must be missing something here ...

```
®mc
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=rm1j&input=WyJvbmUiLCJ0d28iXQ)

Possibly 2 bytes:

```
mq
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=bXE&input=WyJvbmUiLCJ0d28iXQ)

Or stretching it with this 1-byter:

```
U
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVE&code=VQ&input=WyJvbmUiLCJ0d28iXQ)

The first version maps each string in the array to its codepoints and outputs them joined with a space.

The second version splits each string to a character array and outputs them joined with a space.

And the third version, which feels like cheating, just outputs the input with the `-Q` flag doing the heavy lifting of `srringify`ing it.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
jNmC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8sv1/n/f6XEpGQlHQWllNQ0JQA)

This converts each string to base 256 and then joins them in order with a `"`. Since the results are each numbers the `"` unambiguously separates them and the original strings can be recovered with [`mCsdczN`](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P9e5OCW5yu//fzNjCyNDc0slM1NzS1NTCwA).

Comment: @AndersKaseorg suggests a [1-byter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193640/injection-from-two-strings-to-one-string#comment461424_193647).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I've been aware of that since a few minutes after I posted this, I just prefer the spirit of this solution. Thanks for bringing it up anyway, and definitely feel free to post it yourself :)

Comment: I indeed like your answer more as well. :) And nah, I don't even know Pyth. If you want you can post it yourself as a separated answer (or a combined answer by editing this one), otherwise _Anders Kaseorg_ can post it, since he's the one who mentioned it in the comment.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 4 bytes

```
show
```

The Haskell built-in to turn things into strings. The input is taken as a pair of strings.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfbBvzvzgjv/x/bmJmnoKtQko@l4JCQWlJcEmRT56CikKxgoZSYlKyko5SSmqakiampGGMklGMkjFQQUyMkub/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL, 38 bytes

```sql
SELECT QUOTENAME(a)+QUOTENAME(b)FROM i
```

Input is taken from a pre-existing table \$i\$ with `varchar` fields \$a\$ and \$b\$, [per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

Uses [`QUOTENAME`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which surrounds the strings with `[]` and also escapes any internal brackets. Should map to a unique output.

Comment: Same length on MySQL: `SELECT CONCAT(QUOTE(a),QUOTE(b))FROM t` [Try it online](https://rextester.com/WDDN47301)

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 7 bytes

```sh
<<<$@:q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn938bGRsXBqvB/LRdXmoK6ukKxAggoK6TmFpRUKqRlFhWXACWKQVLIEsWpyfl5KRAtECmYTFJ@SQZIHATVoQoUwIwYkMh/AA)

Implicitly joins the arguments on spaces. The `q` modifier tells zsh to quote the arguments, which crucially escapes spaces, ensuring an unescaped space unambiguously separates the two arguments.

(Without `q`, `"a " "b"` and `"a" " b"` would both yield `"a  b"`.)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 1 byte

```
j
```

The code takes an array of two strings as input, and outputs a string representation of that array.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P@v//2r1xKRkdQX1lFT1WgA)

#### Explanation

The code simply reads the input as a string, unevaluated.

Comment: Does this really take two strings as input? It seems like this just prints the input whatever it is.[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P@v//2r1xKRkhcTixJS0xOKUNAA "MATL – Try It Online")

Comment: @DJ It just reads unevaluated input, so it reads anything. Is it a loophole? A more standard approach would be to take the evaluated input as an array and then convert to string representation. But the result would be the same as my code, so I would argue that the distinction is unobservable

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒṘ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of two lists of characters as its argument which yields a single list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7Z/z//z9aKSknMUNJR0EpLT9fvVgpFgA)**

#### How?

It's a built-in to get Python's string representation, simples.

Answer (score 3):

## C# with 26 bytes (thanks to Lukas Lang, Kevin Cruijssen and Jo King)

```
a=>b=>$"{a.Length}.{a}{b}"
```

[tio.run lambda](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrqOAwoHQdnYKaQq2/xNt7ZJs7VSUqhP1fFLz0ksyavWqE2urk2qV/ltzOefnFefnpOqFF2WWpPpk5qVqpGkoGSppaigZJSlpauJSAFYBVvAfAA)

Comment: Please consider using https://tio.run

Comment: This still breaks on ("a<>","b") and ("a","<>b") - note that it is impossible to handle all cases if you're just concatenating the inputs, no matter what you put between/around them - you need to modify the strings somehow

Comment: Sadly, this will still not work - take e.g. ("a","bb") and ("abb","b")

Comment: Sorry, still not enough: take e.g. ("a","..") and ("a..",".")

Comment: ("1","2b") and ("11","b") ;)

Comment: Sorry, still not: ("1","11111111111") and ("11111111111","1") - what does work on the other hand (and is even shorter) is this `$"{a.Length}.{a}{b}"` - you can always extract `a` and `b` from this without any ambiguity (just read until the first `.` to get the length of `a`, `b` is then the rest

Comment: @LukasLang Great. Thanks for the follow ups.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! You can save an additional byte by using currying lambdas `a=>b=>` instead of `(a,b)=>`: [`a=>b=>$"{a.Length}.{a}{b}"`](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrqOAwoHQdnYKaQq2/xNt7ZJs7VSUqhP1fFLz0ksyavWqE2urk2qV/ltzOefnFefnpOqFF2WWpPpk5qVqpGkoGSppaigZJSlpauJSAFYBVvAfAA) Also, if you haven't seen it yet, [tips for golfing in C#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/173/52210) and [tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5285/52210) might be interesting to read through. Enjoy your stay! :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen that's Currying isn't it ? How do you declare the variable to store such function ? (for the current lambda it's `Func<string, string, string>`)

Comment: I asked because I tried, and it won't work: `error CS1593: Delegate 'Func<string, Func<string, string>>' does not take 2 arguments` @JoKing

Comment: Many thanks @JoKing !

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
₁ö
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVPj4W3//0crZaTm5OQr6SgolecX5aQoxQIA)
Interprets each string as a base-256 integer, then prints the two in the form `[1, 2]`.

---

### 05AB1E, 1 byte (unknown validity)

```
â
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8KL//6OVMlJzcvKVdBSUyvOLclKUYgE)

Takes the cartesian product of the input with itself. Quotes in the input are not escaped, which could cause confusion. I brute-forced all combinations of up to 12 `", "` and `"], ["` and didn’t find any collision; however, I can’t prove there aren’t any collisions for longer strings. If anybody can come up with a proof or counter-example, I’d highly appreciate it!

The trivial 0-byter fails because of quotes not being escaped: inputs (`", "`, empty string) and (empty string, `", "`) both yield the output `["", "", ""]`.

The 1-byter `º` (mirror each input string) also fails because of this: inputs (`", "" ,"`, empty string) and (empty string, `" ,"", "`) both yield the output `["", "" ,"", "" ,"", ""]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
⪫Ｅ²⭆⪪Ｓ"⪫""λ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMrPzNPwzexQMNIRyG4BCiUDuIEF@Rklmh45hWUlkAENTR1FJRilJSAFFgHkA3k6SjkaGqCZHSUNDWt//8vyUhVUErLLCouUVIoBuvjAgvlJCJE/uuW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 Ｅ²             Repeat twice
     Ｓ          Input a string
    ⪪ "         Split it on `"`s
   ⭆            Map over each piece and join
       ⪫""λ     Wrap each piece in `"`s
⪫          ,    Join the two results with a `,`
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 22 bytes

<sup>Many fixes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
"$($args|% le*)"+$args
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V9JRUMlsSi9uEZVISdVS1NJG8z7X8vFpaaSpqCUmJSYpKCkoJScogQTUIKKKsDFQBDKBLP/AwA)

Take five, oh my.

Comment: `"ab" "c"` and `"a" "bc"` both produce the same output.

Comment: @JoKing Things should be fixed. Hopefully.

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lP63Y1oBLSSWxKL1YT@l/LReXmkqaglJiUmKSgpKCUnKKEkxACSqqABdTAKmAscHwPwA) with [$OFS](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/psmdtagfaq-what-is-ofs/)?

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 4 bytes

```r
dput
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/paC05H@aRrKGUlp@vpKOUlJikXqxkqbmfwA)

A built-in function which returns the string representation of the input (inspired by [Jonathan Allan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193647/41725) )

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 8 bytes

```
Compress
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zk/t6Aotbj4f2FpfkmqrbK@XmJ8cElRZl66lZ1SQoKSjV2ijZ2SurqSGlcAULTEAawuWlnXLs1BOVZN36Gaq1rJIzUnJ19JRyk8vygnRalWBygUowTkG0HYCjoKQA6UDWQBubVctf8B)

Comment: `{"Hello, ","World"}` and `{"Hello",", World"}` don't they give the same string?

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul ah, nice catch. `Compress` it is then

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>6</s> 3 bytes

```perl6
&dd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfLSXlvzVXmoJNRmpOTr5CeX5RToodXEAhHyrwHwA)

Outputs the object representation to STDERR.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Perl - how would you input a string containing spaces here?

Comment: @negativeseven [like this](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfLSXlvzVXmoJNRmpOTr5CeX5RToodXEAhHy6goaFeXFKUmZeuUJ5ZkqFQXJCYnFqsrqOgrhGjqaSuqWn9HwA)

Comment: @negativeseven Yeah sorry, I was just using a shortcut syntax for lists of strings. You can do that in a typical fashion like `["Hello, ", "World!"]`

Answer (score 1):

## CSS + HTML, 55 + 20 = 75 bytes

Provide the inputs in the HTML after `<code>` tags. Visually injects letters one by one from each input into the output. When an input is longer than the other one, visual spaces are shown for missing letter(s) of the shorter input. Also one comma is added in HTML to force visual output uniqueness (I hope).

```css
*{position:absolute;letter-spacing:9px}code>code{left:9px
```

```html
<code>abcdefg<code>hijklmn</code>,
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 5 bytes

```cs
Print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O@YXJKZn2dTXFKUmZceHWuXZvs/AMgs@W/NlaaRl1oeHVutlJafr6SjlJRYpFSriSQMEtABSwKF/wMA)

Comment: Why the downvote? My solution is perfectly valid

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 27 bytes

```lua
print(('%q%q'):format(...))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ121ULVQXdMqLb8oN7FEQ09PT1Pz////Hqk5Ofk6Ckr/y/OLclIU1QE)

Full program, take input as arguments.

Inspired by zsh answer, as it also use `%q` modifier to use internal safe-string engine.

Also, I can think of just

```lua
('%q%q'):format
```

but I'm not sure if this is acceptable answer.

Comment: I don't think the second is valid since `('%q%q'):format` doesn't result in an object that can, for example, be assigned to a variable. It just causes a syntax error on its own. The colon syntax is just a shortcut for `'%q%q'.format('%q%q', ...)` and Lua doesn't allow partial application for functions

Comment: @JoKing Yeah, you are right, I think.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 19 bytes

```
N
s/ /. /g
s/\n/: /
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/34@rWF9BX09BPx3IiMnTt1LQ//8/0UoBBLmsFBIB)

```
N          # append the second string into the pattern space
s/ /. /g   # prefix all spaces with ".". Now ": " will not occur in the stiring
s/\n/: /   # replace the newline with ": "
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 6 bytes

```javascript
uneval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEtLshMSS3Kzc/LTq38n2b7vzQvtSwx539yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaaRrRSRmpOTr6SjoJSeX5RTopSrKYmF7qSRJB0UjIOyaRkkDRY8j8A)

Input array of strings, output a single string.

Inspired by [Arnauld's JSON.stringify answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193642/44718).

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 59 bytes

Thanks to Grimy for the suggestion.

Takes an array of input strings (of which "2" is the correct number for this challenge) and prints their character values, including the trailing `NUL`. Technically, the `%p` formatter used by `printf` is for pointers, but it works fine for displaying hex values of arbitrary integers if you're not picky about how they look!

```c
f(s,t)char**s,*t;{for(;t=*s++;)for(;printf("%p",*t++)^5;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZHLasMwEEX3@ophIMQPFVJKV8LZdNGPsN3i2lJsUKwgTZtF8Le7khXnsRnuOVzNYtS@HNp2nlXiOKVt39gsczwjcVHGJoKKzOW5SBc42WEkleDmhL6R5@nXu0jFNIdXkLmyLi4Me6m1QY5nY3WHfMcZaqn7oDprzjqqblBKevVt5UhRjYao90q65iij@jBdKH0arVYR1shHsRJG8RggJri5kGC1cG80P22FHJbd6qY8cqie1DZ0tk8mbLmbyu/BCleIWF3Fjk2CMX9DODbDmITQ2EPLIR4w8/CXwoXBKsjXAcLtqXACPAPlxVvsAKz/UW5czcOAYg8lcip3tR@vdSqWnkromk6/5BKsccGJTfM/)

Comment: Nice! Here’s a [59](https://tio.run/##VZHLasMwEEX3@ophIMQPFVJKV8LZdNGPsN3i2lJsUKwgTZtF8Le7khXnsRnuOVzNYtS@HNp2nlXiOKVt39gsczwjcVHGJoKKzOW5SBc42WEkleDmhL6R5@nXu0jFNIdXkLmyLi4Me6m1QY5nY3WHfMcZaqn7oDprzjqqblBKevVt5UhRjYao90q65iij@jBdKH0arVYR1shHsRJG8RggJri5kGC1cG80P22FHJbd6qY8cqie1DZ0tk8mbLmbyu/BCleIWF3Fjk2CMX9DODbDmITQ2EPLIR4w8/CXwoXBKsjXAcLtqXACPAPlxVvsAKz/UW5czcOAYg8lcip3tR@vdSqWnkromk6/5BKsccGJTfM/).

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 0 bytes

Input as an array of 2 strings, output in the format:
`Z = ["{{string 1 stringified}}","{{string 2 stringified}}"]`

Inspired by [Arnauld's JSON.stringify answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193642/44718) and [Doorknob's empty jq answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193651/81957)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/oPBNFKJanFJUo6CkoeqTk5@QolGalFqTpcGfnlColFqQqV@aX2Cp7quQop@Zl56Qr52XpcvolF2QrFiZkpVgoxKJpiYmLykPXFKCnF/o8CAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 9 bytes

```php
serialize
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwMWlkmb7vzi1KDMxJ7Mq9b81F1dqcka@gkqaRrR6YlKyuo6CekpqmnqspvV/AA)

Input is an array of 2 strings like this: `['abc', 'def']`. Uses PHP's [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to serialize the input into a string.

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 11 bytes

```bash
echo ${@@Q}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqFZ/T81OSNfQaXawSGw9n8tF1eagnpGak5OvrqCukJ5flFOijpcCCiiDhdSAokpKSgBVSr9BwA)

`${parameter@Q}` quotes the parameter for reuse as input. In the case of an array, it quotes each element.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 12 bytes

```ruby
->*a{a.to_s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf104rsTpRryQ/vrj2f0FpSbFCWrRSRmpOTr6SjoJSeX5RTopSLBdMIhEkmJSMIpSUDBJEElJXUlKKjo6NVVJS11FXj/0PAA)