# Sum of first n terms of this series

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

Given a digit `x` (between 0 to 9, inclusive) and a number `n`, calculate the sum of the first `n` terms of the following sequence:

\$x,10x+x,100x+10x+x,\dots\$

For example, if `x` is 6 and `n` is 2, then the result will be `6+66` meaning 72.

There can be trailing whitespace in the output but not leading whitespace.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This challenge looks fairly clear, although I'd definitely recommend using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for future challenges.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! I've cleaned up the formatting a bit. I'd also highly recommend using the Sandbox for all challenges; this is a good challenge, but it's good to use it anyway; even I still use it for almost all of mine! As a tip, I'd recommend allowing I/O in "any reasonable format"; we have a pretty well-defined policy on that which is usually good for most challenges where input-output formatting isn't that important. Finally, more test cases usually helps, just to add to clarity and to offer some cases for answerers to test with.

Comment: OK I will use sandbox from next Time

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda x,n:(10**-~n/9-n)/9*x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFCJ89Kw9BAS0u3Lk/fUjdPU99Sq@J/QVFmXolGmoaZjpGmjoKZgraCmZkmF0LUGC4KJlDkTNDkIKSZ5n8A)

-6 thanks to @Bubbler and @tsh

Aha the first answer I have used some math

**How?**

Let's call \$n^{th}\$ term as \$y\$

$$
S_n=x+(10x+x)+(100x+10x+x)+.....+y\\= x+(11x)+(111x)+.....+y\\=\frac{x}{9}(9+99+999+.....+y)\\=\frac{x}{9}((10-1)+(100-1)+(1000-1)+.....+y)\\=\frac{x}{9}((10+100+1000+.....+y)-(1+1+1+.....+1))\\=\frac{x}{9}((10^1+10^2+10^3+...+y)-n)\\=\frac{x}{9}(\frac{10(10^n-1)}{10 - 1}-n)\\=\frac{x}{9}(\frac{10(10^n-1)-9n}{9})\\=\frac{x(10(10^n-1)-9n)}{81}
$$

And we get our magic formula!

Comment: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCJ89Kw9BAS0u3Lk/XUitPU1/fwlCr4n9BUWZeiUaahpmOkaaOgpmCtoKZmSYXQtQYLgomUORM0OQgpJnmfwA) using floored division (29 if you switch to Python 2)

Comment: I'm not quite sure if `(10**-~n/9-n)/9*x` is correct

Comment: @tsh any problem in the formula?

Comment: I'm pretty sure tsh's formula works (and saves one more byte).

Comment: @Wasif I mean maybe you can save one more bytes by using `(10**-~n/9-n)/9*x`

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
RḌ×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o4Y6ew9P///9v8t8MAA)

```
RḌ×    Dyadic link; left arg = n, right arg = x
R      [1..n]
 Ḍ     Undecimal, which is the same as 1 + 11 + ... + (n copies of 1)
  ×    Multiply x
```

---

These are the "backports" of the same algorithm into J and APL:

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

```
*10#.1+i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/tQwNlPUMtTP1/mtycaUmZ@QrmCmkKZj8BwA)

`1+` is needed because J does not have 1-based range built-in.

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 6 bytes

```
10⊥×∘⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///39DgUdfSw9Mfdcx41Lv5f9qjtgmPevsedTUfWm/8qG3io76pwUHOQDLEwzP4v5lCmoIJAA)

*-1 byte thanks to @ovs*

Uses a slightly different algorithm for golfing purposes: multiply `x` to `1..n`, and then evaluate as base 10. This version of the algorithm works in Jelly too: `R×Ḍ`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o8PSHO3r@//9v8t8MAA)

Comment: You can save a byte in APL by multiplying by x before the base 10 decode: https://tio.run/##AUMAvP9hcGwtZHlhbG9n//8xMOKKpcOX4oiY4o2z/2bihpDijY7iioPijazijbTCrzPihpHijpVTUkPijpVUSElT/zYgZiA0

Answer (score 10):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 24 bytes

```javascript
t=>g=n=>n&&t*n+10*g(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/E1i7dNs/WLk9NrUQrT9vQQCtdI0/XUPN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaZpoaRpiYXqqChpoalpuZ/AA)

$$ f(n,x)=\sum_{i=1}^n 10^{n-i}\cdot i\cdot x $$
$$ f(n,x)=nx+10\cdot f(n-1,x) \\ f(0,x)=0 $$

For example, we have:

\$f(6,3)\\
=6+66+666\\
=6+(60+6)+(600+60+6)\\
=600×1+60×2+6×3\\
=((6×1)×10+6×2)×10+6×3\\
=10\cdot f(6,2)+6×3\$

Answer (score 10):

## [Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/excel), 29 bytes

```
=SUM(--REPT(A1,SEQUENCE(A2)))
```

`x` is input in `A1` and `n` is input in `A2`. The formula goes anywhere else in the same sheet.

`SEQUENCE(A2)` creates an array of all the values from 1 to `n`.
`REPT(A1,~)` creates an array of strings of `x` repeated an increasing number of times based on the array created from the previous step.
`--REPT(~)` turns those strings into numbers.
`SUM(~)` adds up those numbers.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 8):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `R`, <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
I*
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=R&code=I*&inputs=4%0A6&header=&footer=)

*Thanks to @AaronMiller for -1*

### 3 bytes, `-rs`

```
ƛ⁰ẋ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=rs&code=%C6%9B%E2%81%B0%E1%BA%8B&inputs=2%0A6&header=&footer=)

;)

### Explained

```
ƛ⁰ẋ
ƛ       # For each number n in the range [1, N]:
 ⁰ẋ     #  return x repeated n times (`-r` makes elements take arguments in reverse order)
        # The `-s` flag sums the top of the stack before outputting
```

### 4 bytes, `s` flag

```
ɾ?vẋ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%C9%BE%3Fv%E1%BA%8B&inputs=2%0A6&header=&footer=)

### 5 bytes, flagless

```
ɾ?vẋ∑
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C9%BE%3Fv%E1%BA%8B%E2%88%91&inputs=2%0A6&header=&footer=)

Comment: [2 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=R&code=I*&inputs=4%0A6&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>11</sup> 8 bytes

```
1#.".\@$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1lPRiHFT@a3KlJmfkKxgppCmom6lDOMYQzn8A)

Assuming I can take the digit as a string...

Taking `3 f '6'` as an example:

- `$` - Duplicate:

  ```
  '666'
  ```
- `".\` Evaluate each prefix:

  ```
  6 66 666
  ```
- `1#.` Sum

  ```
  738
  ```

Answer (score 5):

## MATLAB/Octave, <s>28</s> 26 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```matlab
@(x,n)(1:n)*.1.^(1-n:0)'*x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYpbCoAgEEX/20gzjkn2ECyEVhJI1KdBRrh70yLoMnPhcM@@nPZaY5wgcIcgB4dMSDGDrNxQY8lC3Ix1fiw2ULzBwnq/Hie8ZAwoRQoxrS3vf2umtLY59BXle2TNu5@cKck6hd4njRhv)
Anonymous function.

**How it works**
First of all, sum $$x + (10x + x) + (100x + 10x + x) + ... + (10^{n-1}x + 10^{n-2}x + ... 10x + x)$$
can be transformed to:
$$ n\cdot x + 10(n-1)\cdot x + 100(n-2) \cdot x + ... +10^{n-2} \cdot 2 x + 10^{n-1} x $$
which is:
$$ x \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-i) 10^i  = 
x \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-i)\cdot{0.1^{-i}}$$
Having that established:

- `1:n` is vector containing elements [image: (n-1)], but in reverse order of indexing than above
- `1-n:0` are just indexes of sum above but reversed and negates (so [image: -(n-1), -(n-2), ..., -1, 0])
- `.1.^(1-n:0)` is then vector containing elements [image: 0.1^(-i)] in reversed order of indexing

To get the sum straightforward we would multiply elements of vectors element by element and then sum them like so (whitespace added for readability):

```matlab
sum(  (1:n)  .*   (.1.^(1-n:0))   )
```

However, knowing how matrix multiplication works we can just transpose second vector and by multiplying the matrices:

```matlab
(1:n)  *  (.1.^(1-n:0))'
```

we will get exactly the same result. And at the end we just multiply everything by `x`.

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 41 bytes

```powershell
param($x,$n)iex "$(1..$n|%{"+";"$x"*$_})"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SZlv9vyCxKDFXQ6VCRyVPMzO1QkFJRcNQT08lr0a1WklbyVpJpUJJSyW@VlPpfy0Xl5pKmoKZgtF/AA)

### Explanations

```powershell
iex "$(...)"          # Run as a command the result of the list below, joined using spaces
1..$n|%{"+";"$x"*$_}  # From 1 to n, build a list containing +,x,+,xx,+,xxx,+,xxxx,...
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```r
function(d,n)sum(10^(1:n)-1)*d/9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jRSdPs7g0V8PQIE7D0CpPU9dQUytF3/J/WGpySX5RZlWqRpqmhpmOoZWp5n8A)

$$
x + (10x + x) + (100x + 10x + x) + \ldots = \\
x + 11x + 111x + \ldots = \\
(9x + 99x + 999x + \ldots)/9 = \\
(9+99+999+\ldots)*x/9 = \\
((10-1)+(100-1)+(1000-1)+\ldots)*x/9 = \\
\big[\sum_{i=1}^n(10^i-1)\big]*x/9
$$

*-2 bytes thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)*

---

Using [@Wasif's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225780/55372):

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 34 bytes

```r
function(d,n)d*(10*(10^n-1)/9-n)/9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jRSdPM0VLw9AAhOPydA019S1184DE/zQNMx0jzf8A)

---

Straightforward approach with strings:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>43</s> 39 bytes

```r
function(d,n)sum(strtoi(strrep(d,1:n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jRSdPs7g0V6O4pKgkPxNEFaUWAEUNrfI0NTX/h6Uml@QXZValaqRpapgBRU01/wMA)

*-4 bytes thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)*

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jRSdP09AgTsPQKk/XUFNVSzXPylAr5X9YanJJflFmVapGmqaGmY6hlanmfwA) porting [elementiro's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225816/67312).

Comment: @Giuseppe - nice approach. Do you want to post it youself?

Comment: Sure, [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225922/67312).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ẋḌƤS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hru6HO3qOLQn@//@/2X8TAA)

### Explanation

```
ẋ     repeat `x` `n` times
  Ƥ   for each prefix
 Ḍ    convert it from digits to a decimal number
   S  and sum
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
*dḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Xyvl4Y7F////N/pvBgA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <sup><strike>28</strike></sup> [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX0tBS8NQIaIiTkvbUFOvuDT3vzVXcWKlQpqGmY6R5n8A)

```perl6
* *(1 Xx^*+1).sum
```

Golfed by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) from 28 byte solution:

- Positional arguments `$^a`, `$^b` replaced by whatever-stars
- `Xx` cross metaoperator responsible for generating `1, 11, 111...`

---

#### Original, [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/786WjtWQUMlLulRwzJDzSgtIDNRR0tBy9AAKKClWathpmOkqVecWPn/PwA)

```perl6
{$^a*(^$^b+1).map(1 x*).sum}
```

**Explanation**

- `$^a` is `x`, `$^b` is `n`
- `^$^b+1` is shorthand for `0..^$^b+1`, equivalent to `1..$^b`
- `.map(1 x*)` generates `1, 11, 111...`
- `.sum` adds the `n`-long sequence: 1 for `n=1`, 12, 123, etc.

---

#### Alternative, [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/79aJS5RSyNOJS5J21BTLzexQMNQoUJLU6@4NLdWw9BUxwjITKz8/x8A)

```perl6
{[+] ($^b…1)Z*($^a,* *10…*)}
```

**Explanation**

- `Z*` zip-multiplies two lists, based on the observation that

  - `1E0` appears `n` times
  - `1E1` appears `n-1` times
  - `1E2` appears `n-2` times, etc.

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX0tBS8NQIaIiTkvbUFOvuDT3vzVXcWKlQpqGmY6R5n8A).

Comment: Nice trick there with the `X` operator!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda x,n:(10**n/.9-n)//9*x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCJ89Kw9BASytPX89SN09TX99Sq@J/QVFmXolGmoaZjpGmjoKZgraCmZkmF0LUGC4KJlDkTNDkIKSZ5n8A)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFCJ89Kw9BASytPX89SN09TX99Sq@J/QVFmXolGmoaZjpGmjoKZgraCmZkmF0LUGC4KJlDkTNDkIKSZ5n8A)

Unfortunately I cannot add comments so I'm reposting [Wasif's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225780) with a small tweak so that it works in both python versions. While at it, also correct the math.

$$
S_n=x+(10x+x)+(100x+10x+x)+...+y\\= x+(11x)+(111x)+...+y\\=\frac{x}{9}(9+99+999+...+\frac{9y}{x})\\=\frac{x}{9}((10-1)+(100-1)+(1000-1)+...+(\frac{9y}{x}+1-1))\\=\frac{x}{9}((10+100+1000+...+(\frac{9y}{x}+1))-(1+1+1+...+1))\\=\frac{x}{9}((10^1+10^2+10^3+...+10^n)-n)\\=\frac{x}{9}(\frac{10^{n+1}-10}{9}-n)\\=\frac{x}{9}(\frac{10(10^n-1)-9n}{9})\\=\frac{x(10(10^n-1)-9n)}{81}
$$

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 31 bytes

```r
function(d,n)10^(1:n-1)%*%n:1*d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jRSdP09AgTsPQKk/XUFNVSzXPylAr5X9YanJJflFmVapGmqaGmY6hlanmfwA)

Ports [elementiro's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225816/67312).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda x,n:sum(int(x*-~i)for i in range(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCJ8@quDRXIzOvRKNCS7cuUzMtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VSNPU/N/QRFIOk1D3UxdR8EEKAAA)

Accepts `x` as a string and `n` as an integer. If that's not acceptable, just use `` lambda x,n:sum(int(`x`*-~i)for i in range(n)) `` in Python 2 for +2 (+5 with `str(x)` in Python 3).

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 26 bytes

```
{for(;$2--;b+=a)a=a$1}$0=b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMNaxUhX1zpJ2zZRM9E2UcWwVsXANun/fzMFYwA)

I had an alternate algorithm I thought might be interesting, but it the code was longer...  So this is pretty much a direct translation of the steps in the challenge description.

```
{for(;$2--;    )     }
```

Fir every line of input, the code runs the loop the number of times given by the second input parameter, the `n` value.

```
                a=a$1
```

The body of the loop appends another copy of the first input parameter to the requested digit, meaning the `x` value.

```
           b+=a
```

At the end of each iteration, the accumulator variable `b` is incremented by the current value of the digits placeholder.

```
                      $0=b
```

Finally, once the processing is done, `$0=b` overwrites the input line to display the accumulator value.

The only "trick" here is relying on the way AWK will happily treat variables as both strings and integers.  Meaning, you can append digits together and still do mathematical operations using the results.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pal`, 22 bytes

```perl
map$\+="@F"x$_,1..<>}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlRttWycFNqUIlXsdQT8/Grrb6/38zLuN/@QUlmfl5xf91CxIB)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 24 bytes

```hs
n#x=x*div(10*10^n-9*n)81
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0@5wrZCKyWzTMPQQMvQIC5P11IrT9PC8H9uYmaebUFRZl6JipGy2X8A)

Uses [Wasif's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225780/82619).

### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), also 24 bytes

```hs
0#x=0
n#x=n*x+10*(n-1)#x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/30C5wtaAKw9I5mlVaBsaaGnk6RpqKlf8z03MzLMtKMrMK1ExUjb7DwA)

A port of [tsh's excellent recursive formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225781/82619).

Comment: Looks like the recursive formula from tsh also comes out at 24: [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/30C5wtaAKw9I5mlVaBsaaGnk6RpqKlf8z03MzLMtKMrMK1ExUjb7DwA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input in reverse order.

```
õçV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=9edW&input=NAo2)

```
õçV     :Implicit input of integers U=n & V=x
õ       :Range [1,U]
 çV     :  For each, repeat V that many times
        :Implicit output of sum of resulting array
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>45</s></sup> 43 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%c3%a9goire)!!!

```c
t;s;f(x,n){for(s=t=0;n--;)s+=t=t*10+x;n=s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHtaoMwFP3vU1wEwY/IbJ0tJXN/xp5iypAYO9mWFhNYmPjqczc1ulomeHI959yPXFl8ZGwcFZW08TURQd@cOl/mKk@oiGMayAhjFW6SSFORSzqMrVDwWbXCD5zeAXwMobhUr/qlhBz6A4EdgYzAnkA60LVHTJ4NgS2qBO7ReeXh@syZ4vVfJYhgZ8rhmU1gKmOwn8Ci6YVROoHF@ZinYG9VFyJy9s47bAGmiVvo522hD0/4Zi6B6@/UtZm4FfDNgK2ouca0hNrwAWT7zU@NP48e3FkiXBgKUXRxBzCtbL6uqWRXd9FLupLFLIt/ZYny9NfWPEd@WeRt4rlDS@O7Xk3AqyF@NOjJQuDVNQFBQJJlRTzPZWmrD84w/rDmozrKMf76BQ)

Comment: `t;s;f(x,n){for(s=t=0;n--;)s+=t=t*10+x;n=s;}` saves 2 bytes, similarly to [my Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225907/16236).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 44 bytes

```
[ [1,b] [ 10^ 1 - swap 9 / * ] with map Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BCsIwFET3PcWsRatVFFRwK27ciKtQIcZfDbVJTVKKlJ7G@3ilGGkR/Ks3b/gwGRdOG3887PbbFbi1WlgU3N1iw9WVes4qJZzUqovIySi6d1WlpNAXQmnIuWdppHKw9KhIifC9jpoI4RosMEXbc4L5j2d/PpmE0HoGlgzPKVgQp6BHsDUvscQYA6SoZRhRBPF@IfUN2m745qus4yKP/Qc)

Using the first thing that came to mind,
$$ f(x,n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x}{9}(10^{i} - 1) $$

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/index.html), <s>20</s> 21 bytes

```
~:x;0\),(;{'1'*~x*+}%
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/31jB1KrC2iBGU0fDulrdUF2rrkJLu1b1/38A)

takes as input a string containing n and x, in that order

#### Explanation

```
~:x;0\),(;{'1'*~x*+}%
~                      // parse the input string given
 :x;                   // bind the top value to the x variable
    0\                 // place a zero at the bottom of the stack
      ),(;             // create a list of numbers [1..n]
          {            // begin code block
           '1'*~       // create and evaluate a string of '1's to get the numbers 1, 11, 111...
                x*+    // multiply by x and add to the total (the zero we added)
                   }%  // execute this over every value in the list
                       // implicitly print the stack
```

Comment: You aren't allowed to "assume[] that n and x have been pushed to the stack, with x at the top", that makes the answer a snippet, whereas [only programs and functions are allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/46076) (and this challenge doesn't override the default)

Comment: Fixed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 83 bytes

```cs
(a,b)=>Enumerable.Range(1,b).Sum(x=>Enumerable.Range(0,x).Sum(y=>a*Math.Pow(10,y)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5JfmpSTqpOZV6IDYdoppCnY/tdI1EnStLVzzSvNTS1KBArrBSXmpadqGAKF9YJLczUqsEga6FRAJCtt7RK1fBNLMvQC8ss1DA10KjU1Nf9bcznn5xXnA5WHF2WWpPpk5qVqpGmY6SgYamrilDPCI2cMlPsPAA)

## 39 bytes using @Wasif's formula

```cs
(a,b)=>a*(10*(Math.Pow(10,b)-1)-9*b)/81
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5JfmpSTqpOZV6IDYdoppCnY/tdI1EnStLVL1NIwNNDS8E0sydALyC8HcoDCuoaaupZaSZr6Fob/rbmc8/OK83NS9cKLMktSfTLzUjXSNMx0FAw1NXHKGeGRMwbK/QcA)

## 28 bytes using @tsh's formula

```cs
(a,b)=>b>0?a*b+10*f(a,b-1):0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5JfmpSTqpOZV6IDYdoppCnY/tdI1EnStLVLsjOwT9RK0jY00EoDCekaaloZ/Lfmcs7PK87PSdULL8osSfXJzEvVSNMw01Ew1NTEKWeER84YKPcfAA)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in C#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c) page for ways you can golf your program

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 31 bytes

```
for ((;i++<$2;t+=a))a+=$1
<<<$t
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhb70_KLFDQ0rDO1tW1UjKxLtG0TNTUTtW1VDLlsbGxUSiCqoIqXRZvpKBjFQnkA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
L×O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5/B0////TbjMAA)

```
L       -- list [1..input]
 ×      -- string multiply with input
  O     -- sum
```

Comment: TIO link seems to be taking only one argument...?

Comment: @Bubbler i changed the link to have an example with distinct inputs

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 47 bytes

```
func[x n][t: s: 0 loop n[t: t + s: s * 10 + x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85ukIhLza6xEqh2ErBQCEnP79AIQ/ELVHQBgkVK2gpGBoA2RWxsf@LUgtSE0sU8hTMowuKMvNKos2AbCVdOyWFNAUgE6gCAA)

### Alternative, 55 bytes

```
func[x n][t: copy""s: 0 loop n[s: s + to 1 append t x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxCoAwDAXQ3VN8uoqgi0IHD@EaOohNQZA01Ah6@trtDa9wrBtHCl3yNT1y0AsJZB5H1s@522PElbNCqPlGD8uYsKuyRBjeEGph5d0gWEjLKUZzsxtWh4TGNn4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>30</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
f(x,n)=x(10^n10-10-9n)/81
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2wxk4lkb1c)

[Try It On Desmos!(Prettified)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gm7samiotk)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 20 bytes

```
.+(.)
*$1
L$v`.+
*
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9PW0NPk0tLxZDLR6UsQU@bS4sr/v9/Ix1zLmMdUy4THWMuUx1DAA) Link includes test cases. Takes `n` as the first input. Note: Struggles for large values of `n` (`5` is just about doable). Explanation:

```
.+(.)
*$1
```

Generate `n` copies of `x`.

```
L$v`.+
*
```

Convert each suffix to unary.

```
_
```

Take the sum and convert to decimal.

Comment: A non-Unary version that can handle large values of `n` takes 33 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9PW0NPk0tLxZCrLlpJT/vQNhU9DaUaJa14pVh1LZ@yBD3t//@NdMy5jHXMuEx0TLlMdUy4zHSMucx1jAA "Retina – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
$+YaX\,b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fRTsyMSJGJ@n///9m/40A)

#### Explanation

```
          a & b are command-line args (implicit)
   aX     String-multiply the digit by each number in...
     \,b  inclusive range from 1 through the number of terms
  Y       Yank (to enforce desired precedence)
$+        Fold on addition
          Autoprint (implicit)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 53 bytes

```java
x->n->{int r=0,y=0;for(;n-->0;)r+=y=y*10+x;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVLLiqNAFN3nKw5CQDulaJ4Q2wyzGRiGmSyaWYUsaqI2pk0pVWVQgt@euT7bBjn3es59VB3qyu/cvoYfz@SWZ1LjSv9OoZPUiQtx0UkmnBd/dkm5UvjNE4HHDMiLf2lygdJcU7hnSYgbaeablol4P53B5buy2lLgp9A/@lGvlP8VXFbHPJJcZ/KAGMGztA/CPjwSoSEDl1WB68eZNH1h2wfXt@QiqILqxXMXpS8jXUgB6ddPv51OTaczbdSR0gpBvxN4YMfgMexQs5HaMiwZtlhgu53yG4YVw4b4TQebqbpm7UfCuoMe19Oipp@mkLLqoMchrKbFzSHoKCQtO@hxCGNcTrua29CdSPM66HEIY/xMPNRte92ZRa7CvHPZurXvPLNGyxr/S7KwoU/u2Z/QYqC9L3RU5tFFR@GgLr@oMlJFqkmLHZ7naWWWVpd8V/QOTGENxW@V0tHNyQrt5PSAdGwaZTAPGQThHvNdiLmaC4OhJI71g9m4IPg8yDcYx18G9jD@HI1@QWNBPauf/wE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```ruby
->x,n{(10**-~n/9-n)/9*x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165CJ69aw9BAS0u3Lk/fUjdPU99Sq6L2f4FCWrShjmksF4hhrGMEYRjqGBpAWJY6xrH/AQ)

Stole the formula from [Wasif](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225780/18535).

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 46 bytes

```lua
function f(x,n)return(10*10^n-10-9*n)/81*x end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/rTQvuSQzP08hTaNCJ0@zKLWktChPw9BAy9AgLk/X0EDXUitPU9/CUKtCITUv5X9BUWZeiUaahpmOiabmfwA)

-11 bytes thanks to @Delfad0r

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/rTQvuSQzP08hTaNCJ0@zKLWktChPw9BAy9AgLk/X0EDXUitPU9/CUKtCITUv5X9BUWZeiUaahpmOiabmfwA "Lua – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
Ｉ×Ｎ↨…·¹Ｎχ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEIyQzN7VYwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NHwSmxOBUolpxTWpxZlhqUmJeeqmGoo4CiCqjM0EATCKz//zfjMvqvW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @Bubbler's Jelly answer. This version takes `x` as the first input but it can be trivially modified to take `n` as the first input instead.

```
       Ｎ    `n` as a number
    …·¹     Inclusive range starting at 1
   ↨    χ   Convert from "base 10"
 ×           Multiplied by
  Ｎ          `x` as a number
Ｉ            Cast to string
             Implicitly print
```

By comparison, using string repetition would also take 9 bytes, even if Charcoal supported vectorised string repetition (it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 21 bytes

```
Tr[10^Range@#2-1]/9#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6Qo2tAgLigxLz3VQdlI1zBW31JZ7X9AUWZeiYJDerSZjlHs//8A)

-5 bytes from @att

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6Qo2tAgLigxLz3VQdlI1zBW31JZ7X9AUWZeiYJDerSZjlHs//8A)

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 32 bytes

```
x=>1.to(_).map(x.*(_).toInt).sum
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jYHM1VPDQFenTBsjHukJSw)

I ain't using any of those newfangled formulas! Accepts x as a string, then n as an `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 32 bytes (8 instrs)

```
00000000: e302 0000 e3ff 0000 2aff ffff 28ff ff00  ẉ£¡¡ẉ”¡¡*”””(””¡
00000010: 2202 02ff 2701 0101 5b01 fffc f803 0000  "££”'¢¢¢[¢”‘ẏ¤¡¡
```

```
wrd SET   $2,0              // s = 0
    SET   $255,0            // t = 0
0H  4ADDU $255,$255,$255
    2ADDU $255,$255,$0      // loop: t = t * 10 + x
    ADDU  $2,$2,$255        // s += t
    SUBU  $1,$1,1
    PBNZ  $1,0B             // if(--n) goto loop    
    POP   3,0               // return s
```

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 10 bytes

```
;Z+At^($-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/3zpK27EkTkNF1/D/fzMFYwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
sms*wh
```

[Try it here!](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=sms%2awh&input=2%0A6%0A6&debug=0)

Uses some... creative input trickery. Notice that the problem is a special case of
\$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^jx_j\cdot10^{i\cdot(\lfloor\log_{10}(x_j)\rfloor+1)}\$, where all \$x_i\$ are equal (\$x\$) and \$x\in\mathbb Z,0\le x\le9\$. This solution solves the nonnegative integer case, and takes input as \$n\$, followed by \$x\$ \$n\$ times. For example, for \$x=6,n=2\$, the input is:

```
2
6
6
```

If \$x\$ must only be input once, the solution is [8 bytes](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=ssM%2aLzSE&input=6%0A2&debug=0) <s>and much more boring</s>.