# Randomly capitalize half of a string

Tags: code-golf, string, random

Given string `s` of even length as input, randomly capitalize exactly half of the letters.

- You can assume the input will always be a non-zero, even length
- You can assume the input will consist of only lowercase letters (`[a-z]`)
- Exactly half of the letters should be capitalized in the output
- Every permutation that has exactly half of the characters capitalized should have an equal probability of being output

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes **in each language** wins!

Comment: [moCKiNg sPonGe BOb cAsE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2slkz.png)

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

#### Code

Uses the [05AB1E codepage](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md).

```
ā.rÈÅÏu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SKNe0eGOw62H@0v//09MSk5JTUvPAAA)

#### Explanation

```
             # example input: "abcdefgh"
ā            # Indices of the input                   -> ex. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
 .r          # Randomly shuffle this list             -> ex. [5, 4, 6, 3, 2, 8, 1, 7]
   È         # Map (x % 2 == 0) on each element       -> ex. [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
    ÅÏ       # Apply the following on truthy indices:
      u      #   Convert to uppercase                 -> ex. "aBCdEFgh"
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 86 bytes

```
lambda s:bytes(map(int.__xor__,s,sample(len(s)//2*[0,32],len(s))))
from random import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxLCsIwFEXnrqLg5KXEVOpEhG7DiUpImhcsNB-SFOxanBTE7sndGEjv5H64nPfq5_R0dvno7v6dkj6cf9dRGKlEFS9yThjBCA-DTYzzlwuc00ijMH5EGNFCJE3T1rcjPbUPWoasnQ7OVEFYlW0w3oVUb_S9DxkGOiP9lIAwtL1TCIQwhVsq12UVsleoS_sD)

Uses [Rɪᴋᴇʀ's idea](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59760574) to toggle case using `^32`, but taken a bit further.

-1 byte thanks to @ovs.

Comment: [-1](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxLCsIwFEXnrqLg5KXEVOpEhG7DiUpImhcsNB-SFOxanBTE7sndGEjv5H64nPfq5_R0dvno7v6dkj6cf9dRGKlEFS9yThjBCA-DTYzzlwuc00ijMH5EGNFCJE3T1rcjPbUPWoasnQ7OVEFYlW0w3oVUb_S9DxkGOiP9lIAwtL1TCIQwhVsq12UVsleoS_sD) with `sample` instead of `shuffle`

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 8 bytes

```
ŒuJḂẊTƲ¦
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FuuPTir1erij6eGurpBjmw4tW1KclFwMlVsVrZSYlJySmqYUCxUBAA)

Using the mod-2 trick from [Adnan's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237903/97857).

Explanation:

```
ŒuJḂẊTƲ¦

Œu   TƲ¦   uppercase at truthy indices:
  J          range [1..length(input()]
   Ḃ         each modulo 2
    Ẋ        random permutation
```

`JḂ` essentially creates `[0, 1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 1]` up to the length of the input.

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 9 bytes

```
ŒuJẊŒHḢƲ¦
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FhuPTir1erir6-gkj4c7Fh3bdGjZkuKk5GKo7KpopcSk5JTUNKVYqAgA)

Explanation:

```
ŒuJẊŒHḢƲ¦

Œu     Ʋ¦   uppercase at indices:
  JẊ          random permutation of [1..length(input)]
    ŒH        split that list into two halves
      Ḣ       take the first of those two halves
```

I think there ought to be a shorter way of doing the `JẊŒHḢ`, <s>perhaps by picking a random combination</s><sup>[nope](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FuuPTir1Ojo52cdDJeLYpkPLlhQnJRdD5VZFKyUmJaekpinFQkUA)</sup>. Or, at least, a shorter version of `ŒHḢ`.

Comment: nice golf, the 0,1,0,1 array is clever

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>52</s> <s>51</s> 33 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 25 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with `\`.

```r
function(s)s-sample(seq(s))%%2*32
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jWLNYtzgxtyAnVaM4tRDI1VRVNdIyNvqfmVcSkh9akmahkaZRCqRC8j3zSjSUEpOUNDU1uciUTU5JTUvPAKv5DwA)

Inputs and outputs through vector of character codes.

Inspired by [@Adnan's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237903/55372).

Comment: I got [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##bczNCoAgEATgd1kQFDx172E2XcvwLy3o7Wvo3OFjYGCmP52Lr3njFK7WpDseMj/hKu6MtejbxCBpiB6cW0LIgU6pydjbnvWboDB/N9ppYrK0gAMPAgFW2CDCTti/) using characters instead of character codes, but I'll never beat 33...

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>14</s> 9 bytes

−5 bytes thanks to ovs.

Anonymous tacit prefix function

```apl
⌈@(2|≢?≢)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1FPh4OGUc2jzkX2QKz5P@1R24RHvX2Pupof9a551Lvl0HrjR20TH/VNDQ5yBpIhHp7B/9PUM1JzcvLL84tyUtQB)

`⌈` uppercase

`@(`…`)` at the positions indicated by the following mask:

`≢?≢` shuffle the indices 1 through the tally of elements in the argument (lit. take n random elements from 1…n, without replacement)

`2|` division remainders when divided by 2

Comment: I think [`⌈@(2|≢?≢)`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1FPh4OGUc2jzkX2QKz5P@1R24RHvX2Pupof9a551Lvl0HrjR20TH/VNDQ5yBpIhHp7B/9PUM1JzcvLL84tyUtQB) works for 9

Comment: @ovs Yes, of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```c
i,r;f(*s,z){for(i=z;s[r=rand()%z]>96?s[r]-=32,i-=2:i;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrRCsIgFADQ931FCINrKKwFQYn1A/3B2INsWhechgqBY99urtfDmfhklXuVgiwIA8fIMl2ND4AyizgEGZSbgbZ5vF8vjwojl@eeIZf9DQUVW1kUOqBrE/8z4aKho1Q06NIh6ZiGUT7JW1vrvz7YmYjGwO7s1NX1CfUZIK2NhO1cbSs/)

- takes a pointer to a widechar string and modifies it.

Comment: I think `i--` should be `--i` instead. Otherwise you can get an additional uppercase character.

Comment: Thanks @ovs , btw while fixing it I found a way to save another 1

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 76 bytes

```javascript
f=s=>(S=Buffer(s).map(c=>c^=Math.random(n++)<.5?32:--n-n--,n=0),n?f(s):S)+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvBCoMwDADQf/FiQm0ZG7vIorD7Tt4HpbabQxNp1N/v5J3fzx9eQ57WzbKMsZRESh0M9NxTihkU3eJXCNSFN7389nXZ8ygLsDH4cPf@dm2t5ZNtmC7YcJ/O1A5o6roEYZU5ulk@kKDaeTpi1lghlj8)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = s =>               // s = input string
( S =                  // S = output
  Buffer(s)            // turn s into a buffer
  .map(c =>            // for each ASCII code c in s:
    c ^=               //   update c:
      Math.random(n++) //     increment n
      < .5 ?           //     with 1/2 probability:
        32             //       turn c into uppercase
      :                //     or:
        --n - n--,     //       leave c unchanged and decrement n twice
    n = 0              //   start with n = 0
  ),                   // end of map()
  n ? f(s)             // try again if we haven't capitalized exactly
                       // half of the letters
    : S                // otherwise, stop and return S
)                      //
+ ''                   // coerce the output buffer back to a string
```

Comment: `--n-n--` haha this part is clever, but a nightmare to read, dont forget your priorities!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 154 bytes

*-1 thanks to emanresu A, with their `v<{}` trick*

```
s=>(t=(f=x=>x?f(x.slice(1)).flatMap(y=>[x[0]+y,x[0].toUpperCase()+y]):[""])(s).filter(w=>![...w].reduce((u,v)=>u+(v<{})*2-1,0)))[Math.random()*t.length|0]
```

**Explanation:**

- `(f=x=>x?f(x.slice(1)).flatMap(y=>[x[0]+y,x[0].toUpperCase()+y]):[""])(s)`: Recursively finds all ways to capitalize the string
- `.filter(w=>![...w].reduce((u,v)=>u+(v<{})*2-1,0))`: Filters out items which don't have the correct number of capitalized letters, by checking if the sum of `-1` (for capitalized) and `1` (for lowercase) is `0`
- `[Math.random()*t.length|0]`: Choose a random item

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 21 bytes

```
toupper@{~`]`[}-:@#?#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/S/JLCwpSixyq6xJiE6Jrda0clO2V/2typSZn5CukKagnJiWnpKalZ6iTJ/IfAA)

- `-:@#?#` Randomly "Deal" `?` half-the-length `-:@#` number of indices from all possible indices.
- `toupper@{~`]`[}` And Amend `}` just those indices with their uppercased versions `toupper@{~`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 8 bytes

```
JẊị"żŒu$
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCJK4bqK4buLXCLFvMWSdSQiLCIiLCIiLFsiaGVsbG93b3JsZCJdXQ==)

-2 bytes thanks to a clever trick from Adnan using cyclical indexing, thus tying pxeger's answer

```
JẊị"żŒu$    Main Link
J           [1, 2, ..., len(input)]
 Ẋ          random permutation of that
  ị"        vectorize - index (half of them are even, half are odd, and it wraps)
    żŒu$    the input zipped with itself capitalized
```

Comment: I actually had a version that used `Ø.` ... `Ẋ` but had something longer than `ṁ`; I wonder if I can combine it to get something shorter.

Comment: You can replace `Ø.ṁ` with `J`, as Jelly supports cyclic indexing: [`JẊị"żŒu$`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/r4a6uh7u7lY7uOTqpVOX///@JSckpqWnpGQA).

Comment: Much less smart than what Adnan just suggested, but if you replace `ị"żŒu$` with `Œu` ... `TƲ¦` you get 9 bytes: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FhuPTio9PEPv4c7Gh7u6Qo5tOrRsSXFScjFUdlW0UmJSckpqmlIsVAQA

Comment: Alternatively, `Ø.ṁ` can be `JḂ` as in [my second answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237897) (which was taken from [@Adnan's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237903))

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `sequences.repeating`, <sup><s>43</s></sup> 39 bytes

```
[ "\0 "over length cycle randomize v- ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcw7CgIxFAXQflZxSe9grQsQGxuxUosYr0kwn5mXTEA3HxEE@8N5aFOz9NNxf9ht8KQkBhTOC5Nhgeh0zxFRVzc2fmmBz38wCifq6pPFdhiU0/G2iKUU1c9QlzVUbhQEJlsdzMsE/k7/JtoK1250CJjEp9o/)

```
            ! "hamburgers"
"\0 "       ! "hamburgers" "\0 "
over        ! "hamburgers" "\0 " "hamburgers"
length      ! "hamburgers" "\0 " 10
cycle       ! "hamburgers" "\0 \0 \0 \0 \0 "
randomize   ! "hamburgers" "\0\0\0    \0 \0"
v-          ! "hamBURGeRs"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>58</s> 51 bytes

-1 thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237895/randomly-capitalize-half-of-a-string/237931?noredirect=1#comment539485_237931)
-6 with wide string and clang

```c
i;f(*s,l){for(i=l/2;rand()%l--<i?s[l]^=32,--i:i;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1LjsIwEETX@BTGEsgmtiYEVjgWF@AGmYwUmQS15HSQnfmIiLOHJqtZdavqVZU3PjR4m2ewndwlHdTUDVGCCx@FjQ1epdoEY0o4pyrUX@5QaGPgBFbZ59w3gFJNDHDkgFXNHb@IxrfQ4xDT98/v30PYxQ0tcnL3R8tYWmpH6FuZK2VZJwH1m6D/HonupNiE9IlCw1tbCvxI8ZzgIXK57LnccigpRifLFFsRkjm@JreCenso/tddhfYjCc/5BQ)

Outputs by modifying the input string.

Each letter has a \$\frac in\$ chance of being capitalized, where \$i\$ is the number of remaining capital letters and \$n\$ is the number of remaining letters (including this one).

Comment: Very interesting! You can also [switch to clang](https://tio.run/##TY3dqsIwEISvT54iBjwkNsFavTKG8wK@Qa1QYisL6VaS@sMRn72uvfJql5lvZrzxocbzOIJt5SLpoJ5tHyW4sCxssLHGk1TzYMwO/sAYncpQHd262ObKvsauBpTqyQAHDlhW3PG9qH0DHfYxXW/3x7@wk8tDg5zs1cYylqbaAbpG5kpZ1kpA/SHov0TCWynmIR1QaPhoU4MfKJ4T3Ecup0GXWw47itHJMsV@CMkcn5FbQvW7Lr7rTkL7gYTX@AY "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Comment: And save another 1 by merging condition+increment [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1LjsIwEETX@BTGEsgmtiYEVjgWF@AGmYwUmQS15HSQnfmIiLOHJqtZdavqVZU3PjR4m2ewndwlHdTUDVGCCx@FjQ1epdoEY0o4pyrUX@5QaGPgBFbZ59w3gFJNDHDkgFXNHb@IxrfQ4xDT98/v30PYxeWhRU72/mgZS0vvCH0rc6Us6ySgfhP03yPhnRSbkD5RaHhrS4MfKZ4TPEQul0GXWw4lxehkmWIrQjLH1@RWUG8Pxf@6q9B@JOE5vwA "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 59 bytes

```ruby
->s{[*0...q=s.size].sample(q/2).map{|w|s[w]=s[w].upcase};s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664OlrLQE9Pr9C2WK84syo1Vq84MbcgJ1WjUN9IUy83saC6prymOLo81hZE6JUWJCcWp9ZaF9f@L1BIi1YqSS0uUYr9DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 73 bytes

```julia
!s=(E=length(s);v=rand(E);prod(i->s[i]-32*(i∈sortperm(v)[1:E÷2]),1:E))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BDoIwFET3nKKw@t8AQnUlqTtOQdA0UrUGCukvxCNwIw/gTbwIQkh09SaZvMw8@lrL9DlNPgnIRa3Mzd2BMBuElaaCHLPOthXo6EiFLqMd34D@jCO11nXKNjBgkR7y94uXGM4BcXKK3PkiSRETrAhkcOIhW7BfkSYreVJ63rW1jJg27G95ndXG1Qaob0BT3807SxFD4VMcxyUiE4L9rm45espU0xc)

Answer (score 3):

## Uiua, <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
⍜▽⌵◿2⍏≡⋅⚂.
```

[Try it](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4o2c4pa94oy14pe_MuKNj-KJoeKLheKagi4KCkYgImFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6Igo=)

-2 thanks to chunes’s nice idea to use [gap `⋅`](https://uiua.org/docs/gap).

Explanation:

```
≡⋅⚂.
```

To each of the input’s [rows `≡`](https://uiua.org/docs/rows), drop the item with [gap `⋅`](https://uiua.org/docs/gap) and give a [random `⚂`](https://uiua.org/docs/random) value between 0 and 1.

```
⍏
```

[rise `⍏`](https://uiua.org/docs/rise) gives the index of each number if you had sorted the list in ascending order.

```
◿2
```

Take each number [modulus `◿`](https://uiua.org/docs/modulus)2.

```
⍜▽⌵
```

[under `⍜`](https://uiua.org/docs/under) [keep `▽`](https://uiua.org/docs/keep) basically takes a list of 1’s and 0’s and a list of the same length, and applies a function to every item in the second list corresponding with a 1 in the first. [absolute value `⌵`](https://uiua.org/docs/absolute%20value), if given a character, uppercases it.

Comment: [-2](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4o2c4pa94oy14pe_MuKNj-KIteKLheKagi4KCkYgImFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6Igo=) no need to make a new list of random numbers, just stick them in a copy of the input.

Comment: @chunes nice, that was my first idea but i had `rows(rand pop)` because i forgot about gap

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 81 bytes

```
/^((?<-2>[a-z])|(?<-3>[A-Z])|([A-Z])|([a-z]))*(?(2)^)(?(3)^)$/^+/./_?(T`l`L
T`L`l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F8/TkPD3kbXyC46UbcqVrMGxDG2i3bUjQJx4DRYUlNLw17DSDNOE0gZAykV/ThtfT39eHuNkIScBB@ukASfhJz//5MTCzJLEnMyi1O5ihLzUvJzcyoB) Explanation:

```
/^((?<-2>[a-z])|(?<-3>[A-Z])|([A-Z])|([a-z]))*(?(2)^)(?(3)^)$/
```

Check whether the input contains equal numbers of lower and upper case letters. Groups `2` and `3` contain any excess upper and lower case letters respectively; if they are non-empty then the letter of the opposite case decrements the group, otherwise the letter increments the group appropriately. At the end both groups are required to be empty.

```
^+
```

Repeat while it does not.

```
/./_
```

Loop over each letter.

```
?(
```

Random choice between one of the following.

```
T`l`L
```

Uppercase.

```
T`L`l
```

Lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),<strike>127</strike> 119 bytes

Not super happy with this, I'll probably come back to it after class (or not, we'll see). Takes input from stdin using Python 2 `input()` rules - aka `"test"` rather than `test`.

Requires Python 2 for `range` returning a list, since that would require `*x,` instead of `x` otherwise, and would lose a byte on the print statement and I don't think you can gain more than 2 from inline variable assignments.

Using `chr`/`ord` is shorter than `[s[i],s[i].upper()][i in x[::2]]`, I think that's optimal as well.

Thanks to enzo for -8, from switching from using a while loop to just `str.join`.

```python
from random import*
s=input()
n=len(s)
r=range(n)
x=sample(r,n)
print''.join(chr(ord(s[i])-32*(i in x[::2]))for i in r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCoMwEADveUXw4q60PaQ3IS8RD1Jj3WJ2wyaCfX0aehpmmPQtu7CrdVOJVhdeGygm0TKY7InTWQAN@yMwZDTq2/MOwGgun5eYjgB6a5aUuPT94yPE8NoVRFfIE814f7oByBLbaxpHNyNuovYfFGvtSsil@wE)

Comment: [119 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYpBCoMwEADveUXw4q60PaQ3IS8RD1Jj3WJ2wyaCfX0aehpmmPQtu7CrdVOJVhdeGygm0TKY7InTWQAN@yMwZDTq2/MOwGgun5eYjgB6a5aUuPT94yPE8NoVRFfIE814f7oByBLbaxpHNyNuovYfFGvtSsil@wE) using str.join instead of a while loop.

Comment: @enzo oh, good catch, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 52 bytes

```
MapAt[Capitalize,#,RandomSample[i=0;{++i}&/@#,i/2]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zexwLEk2jmxILMkMSezKlVHWScoMS8lPzc4MbcgJzU609bAulpbO7NWTd9BWSdT3yg2Vu1/QFFmXomDVnAJkE73ys/MU3BId3DOSCxKTC5JLSqOVioCG1EMlleK/f8fAA)

-16 bytes thanks to @att

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zexwLEk2jmxILMkMSezKlVHWScoMS8lPzc4MbcgJzU609bAulpbO7NWTd9BWSdT3yg2Vu1/QFFmXomDVnAJkE73ys/MU3BId3DOSCxKTC5JLSqOVioCG1EMlleK/f8fAA) outputting as a character list

Answer (score 2):

#### In true Perl spirit, [TMTOWTDI](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TMTOWTDI):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=shuffle -F`, 35 bytes

```perl
map$_=uc,(shuffle@F)[1..@F/2];say@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAl3rY0WUejOKM0LS0n1cFNM9pQT8/BTd8o1ro4sdLB7f//xKTklNS09H/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA2AtE9mcYmVVWhJZo4tVP9/XTcA)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-F`, 49 bytes

```perl
@k{0..$#F}=1;map$_=uc,@F[(keys%k)[1..@F/2]];say@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/98hu9pAT09F2a3W1tA6N7FAJd62NFnHwS1aIzu1slg1WzPaUE/PwU3fKDbWujix0sHt///EpOSUf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7rugEA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/%3E!), 145 bytes

Hey! I'm completely new to this and my answer will make that apparent. I thought I'd post so that I can refer back to later to see my progress. Let me know if I anything is incorrect involving my answer.

didn't include logging, output is the t string

```
string t="";int p=0;while(p!=s.Length/2){t="";p=0;foreach(char c in s){char l=c;if(new Random().Next(2)==0){l=char.ToUpper(l);p++;}t=$"{t}{l}";}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BSgMxGITP3af4DR4Sirul15CTLHiotrRZVMRDSNPdQDZZkmiVkGdf03rRuc3MNzAy3Enn1Tx/BG17OHyHqEZaSSNCgJ13vRcjpGoRoohawqfTR3gU2uIQfRm8vYPwfSAXBIp@UwjAAA3KGEShaXYdh9dttwfevnB4aPct8G0xB/5vFBlCVNsIE1vR86CNwtMNC/VG2T4OzZqkK3FpT@WykAOWg/AgQVsIJF2NYZLqE7bqDHthj27EpH5SXxGvCWMrkkpfsJq7bpqUx4bQabmkObJblGJOJiOacwV/dO9scEbVz15HtdFW4UhotchVnucf)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Using predefined variables for input or outputting by defining a variable are not permitted input formats according to our [site-wide default policy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), and the challenge poster has not modified these rules. However, you can define a function that takes `s` as an argument and returns `t`, which would be permitted by the default policy. This is a great first answer though, and I look forward to seeing your progress too :)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in C#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/173/66833) page for ways you can golf your program. Unfortunately, assuming the input/output is in a variable (`s` and `t` here) isn't an [acceptable method of I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/66833). I suggest either turning this into a function or a full program

Answer (score 2):

## [ayr](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/ayr), 13 bytes

```
(];-){:2|#?.#
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/ayr#Zjo@/KF07LSl7OjJ8Iz8uIw@@/Oz5mIjEwJEAuMCBfMV0nYWJjZGVmZ2gn//)

## Explained

```
       #?.# Roll N-sided die N times, where N is len of y
     2|     Convert this to a length-N boolean vector (half 1s, half 0s)
   {:       Use this to catalogue..
];-         A matrix of the string and the string with inverted caps
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ẏṖ℅Ih⁽N¨M
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuo/huZbihIVJaOKBvU7CqE0iLCIiLCJzdHJpbmciXQ==)

Explanation:

```
ẏ         # List of [0..len(input))
 Ṗ℅       # Random permutation
   Ih     # First half of the list
     ⁽N¨M # Toggle case of the indexes in the list
```

There is actually a dedicated builtin for `Random Permutation`, which is faster, but there is a bug in it, so we have to get every permutation and choose a random one.

Comment: There's no bug anymore

Comment: @lyxal [u sure bout that?](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIxMMqAcyDDnuKEhSIsIiIsIiJd) (looks like another LazyList bug)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 105 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join([x,x.upper()][y%2]for x,y in zip(s,sample([*range(len(s))],len(s))))
from random import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpBDsIgEADvvoKL6dKQHvRm4ktqDxjAYmB3s9BI/Tz24GkmmeG9roTXHu6Pnmx@OqvKbRimN0WEuZk2bcxeQC/zfr4sgUQ1s6uI6hsZiik2c/Iwj2Lx5SF5hKL1Yv6i9SkIZXVUdyBmJqljZ4lYIUBE3iocV199SvQhSa7/AA)

Comment: The `range()` iterable is enough for `sample()`, no need to convert it to `list`: `sample(range(len(s)),len(s))`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF`, 43 bytes

1 byte saved thanks to [@Kjetil S](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64733/kjetil-s)!

```perl
$F[rand@F]&=_,$_=join"",@F
while@F/2>y;A-Z;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/FLbooMS/FwS1WzTZeRyXeNis/M09JScfBjas8IzMn1cFN38iu0tpRN8r6///EpOSU1LT0jH/5BSWZ@XnF/3UL3AA)

---

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pa`, 38 bytes

-5 bytes using a space separates string (Thanks [@Kjetil S](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64733/kjetil-s)!)

```perl
$F[rand@F]&=_,$_="@F"
while@F/2>y;A-Z;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/FLbooMS/FwS1WzTZeRyXeVsnBTYmrPCMzJ9XBTd/IrtLaUTfK@v//RIUkhWSFFIVUhTSFdIWMf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsSAQ)

Comment: Good answer! `@F*rand` can be replaced by `rand@F`. Also, if you agree, since nothing in the challenge clearly forbids adding a space between the letters in the output `join"",@F` can be replaced by `$_="@F"` to save 5 extra bytes.

Comment: @KjetilS Yes of course! I've been golfing on my phone and sure I tried `rand@F` which didn't work for some reason and stopped using it, but I probably just messed it up somehow! Thank you! The list of chars might be pushing it a little but I've added it too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 89 bytes

```
=LET(x,LEN(A1),y,RANDARRAY(x),CONCAT(CHAR(CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(x),1))-(y>MEDIAN(y))*32)))
```

This breaks the string into an array of characters. Then generates an array of random numbers of the same length.  For each number in the random array that is greater that the median of the array, the corresponding letter is changed to upper case (ASCII value reduced by 32).  Then all of the characters are concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 41 bytes

```
{[~] {@_[pick @_/2,^@_]».=uc;@_}(.comb)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OrouVqHaIT66IDM5W8EhXt9IJ84hPvbQbj3b0mRrh/haDb3k/Nwkzdr/xYmVCmka6mn5@UmJReqaCmn5RQpxhgb/AQ)

- `.comb` splits the input string into a list of characters, which is then fed to the brace-delimited anonymous function, which takes the list in the `@_` array.  This is just a short way to get an array with writeable elements without having to declare one explicitly.
- `pick @_ / 2, ^@_` randomly selects half of the indices in the character array.
- `@_[...]».=uc` slices into the array of characters with the random selection of indices, and uppercases the characters at those indices.  The original array is then returned.
- `[~]` concatenates the characters into a single string.

Answer (score 1):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang), 100 bytes

```
=1'±""=a®1=b$a/=i`1=r¢1,a-=c¥r,1=u$32`2!t$u»}3,c,3!u+|2`3!u}2,91-32»!¤r,u!i+}2,b=i`4=c¥i,1~!i+}2,a,4
```

explanation:

```
=1'±""=a®1=b$a/=i`1=r¢1,a-=c¥r,1=u$32`2!t$u»}3,c,3!u+|2`3!u}2,91-32»!¤r,u!i+}2,b=i`4=c¥i,1~!i+}2,a,4             packed
=1'                                                                                                              get user input and set it to var1
   ±""                                                                                                           split it every character (to bypass a bug in the yasepl code)
      =a®1                                                                                                       A = length of var1
          =b$a/                                                                                                  B = length of var1 divided by 2
               =i                                                                                                increment variable
                 `1                                                      !i }2,b                                 do while I < B...
                   =r¢1,a-=c¥r,1                                                                                 C = character from var1 at random position
                                =u$32`2!t$u»}3,c,3!u+|2`3!u}2,91                                                 if C is uppercase then continue loop, do not increment. if not, continue
                                                                -32»!¤r,u                                        make character at the position lowercase in list
                                                                           +                                     increment I
                                                                                =i`4=c¥i,1~!i+}2,a,4             join list together once done and print it
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
Ｗ⁻⊗ＬΦＫＡ№ακＬθＰ⭆θ‽⁺κ↥κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BCsIwEEWvMsspxBO4EsWVgaL0AGM6tEPGJE0TPX4M4t88Pjz@dytlF0lb@6yiDGgl1B0vsT6VZ7xxWMqKV9HCGUdmf1LFwcA51lCQDPihx8Bf3HoBW7VIytKFR@lYLCXcDNwpzPGFo/YDb2BKibOjnfG3MRxbc5SkkMrO7fDWLw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｗ⁻⊗ＬΦＫＡ№ακＬθ
```

Repeat until uppercase letters make up exactly half of the canvas...

```
Ｐ⭆θ‽⁺κ↥κ
```

... output the input string but randomly uppercase each letter.

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 37 bytes

Prompts for string

```
s[i]←s[i←(.5×⍴s)?⍴s←⎕av⍳⎕]+48⋄⎕av[s]
```

[Try it online!Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tf3F0ZiyQB6SApIae6eHpj3q3FGvag0igCFB1Ytmj3s1AOlbbxOJRdwtYJLo4lus/UD/X/zQu9cSk5JTUNHUA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 124 bytes:

```
import random as r
j=range
f=lambda s:(lambda v:''.join(chr(ord(s[i])-32*(i in v))for i in j(l)))(r.sample(j(l:=len(s)),l//2))
```

Answer (score 0):

`(new Array(s.length)).fill(0).map((i,j)=> j % 2).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).map((i, j) => (i ? s[j].toUpperCase() : s[j])).join("")`

Comment: This site is for code golf. And shorter answer is better. So you may try to minimize your byte count by at least remove unnecessary space characters. Also, you should include what language you are using and the byte count in the post. And it would be even better if a code snippet or link to online runner is provided so everyone may test your code.

Comment: How does this take input?  It doesn't look like it has input.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This doesn't actually have a uniform chance of capitalizing the different characters, as `.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)` is a biased way to shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 44 bytes

```
irysp>l[0f1f,,]p<[>sprl0y?[,sprl]psp<l' *-o]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zqLK4wC4n2iDNME1HJ7bAJtquuKAox6DSPloHxIgtKC6wyVFX0NLNj/3/vzg/N7UkIzMvPbM4I7GgIDUPyAQA)

This one works by generating a list of `0 1` pairs on a list the size of the input string.  Then for each input character it reverses the list of `0 1` pairs a random number of times, then pops the top off the resulting stack.  That value is used to decide whether or not to capitalize the character before printing it out.

1. Prep the input strings

```
ir      - read input codepoints into the stack, reverse the stack
  ysp   - save the number of char, delete that from the stack
     >  - switch to an empty stack
```

2. Generate a list of `0 1` pairs

```
      l[0f1f,,]p
      l[    ,,]p  - loop "n/2" times adding "0,1" pairs to the stack
        0f        - add a "0" to the stack, pull the iterating var forward
          1f      - add a "1" to the stack and pull the iterator forward again
```

3. Process each of the input chars on the input stack

```
<[                         ] - loop until the input stack is empty
  *3.1*                      - get a random 0/1 from the boolean stack
                    <l       - back to input stack, load boolean 0/1 capitalization choice
                      ' *    - multiple " " by the boolean
                         -   - subtract to capitalize (of boolean was true)
                          o  - print the current input char
```

3.1 Pull a random boolean off the list

```
>                   - switch to the boolean stack
 sprl               - disrupt pattern on list, move top entry to the bottom
     0y?            - pick a random number between 0 and the stack size
        [,sp l]p    - loop that number of time, using backup cell for iterator val
            r       - reverse the stack
                sp  - save the random boolean to the backup cell
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
δ^hr¥áÅ;v^mÅ~§
```

I/O as a list of characters.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///clriMokNLDy883GpdFpd7uLXu0PL//6PVS9R11FOBuBiIQexMIM4D4nT1WK5o9UQgKwmIk4E4BYsISC92UR31NLApOuoZUFOzgDgbiHOAOBdqSz4QFwBxIRAXIbmiFIjLgLgciCuAuBKIq9RjAQ)

**Explanation:**

```python
δ              # Capitalize each character in the (implicit) input-list
               #  e.g. ['a','b','c','d','e'] → ['A','B','C','D','E']
 ^             # Zip it with the (implicit) input-list
               #  → [['a','A'],['b','B'],['c','C'],['d','D'],['e','E']]
  h            # Push the length (without popping)
               #  → 5
   r           # Pop and push a list in the range [0,length)
               #  → [0,1,2,3,4]
    ¥          # Mod-2 on each
               #  → [0,1,0,1,0]
     á         # Sort it by,
      Å        # using the following 2 characters as inner code-block:
       ;       #  Discard the value
        v      #  Push a random integer in the range [-2147483648,2147483647]
               #  e.g. [0,1,0,0,1]
         ^     # Zip these shuffled 0s/1s with the earlier pair of characters
               #  → [[['a','A'],0],[['b','B'],1],[['c','C'],0],[['d','D'],0],[['e','E'],1]]
          m    # Map over each,
           Å   # using 2 characters as inner code-block again:
            ~  #  Dump the pair and integer separated to the stack
             § #  Index the integer into the pair
               #  → ['a','B','c','d','E']
               # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 160 bytes

```
Input Str1
length(Str1
Ans/2≥randIntNoRep(1,Ans→S
"abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ→Str2
".
For(I,1,dim(ʟS
Ans+sub(Str2,inString(Str2,sub(Str1,I,1))+26ʟS(I),1
End
sub(Ans,2,dim(ʟS
```

Output is stored in `Ans` and displayed. Only works on calculators that support `randIntNoRep(`.

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 142 bytes

```sql
SELECT top(len(@)/2)@=stuff(@,number+1,1,upper(substring(@,number+1,1)))FROM
spt_values WHERE number<len(@)and'P'=type
ORDER BY newid()PRINT @
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1525346/randomly-capitalize-half-of-a-string)**

This will always give return the same result. In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, the result is randomized. The reason could be the explanation below by Fmbalbuena

Comment: The "Try it online" is not actual SQL Interpreter, its Stack Exchange Data Explorer Interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>88</s> 86 bytes

```javascript
f=s=>(r=s.replace(/./g,c=>Math.random()>.5?c:c.toUpperCase(a+=2),a=0)).length-a?f(s):r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc2xCsIwFEDR3a8onRJsUxEEEVIRZ0cXxeH5TFM1TWKSVs3PVx0EFRzvcLgn6MCjO9qQd9O@r7jnJXHcMyesAhSkYIXMkJcrCDVzoA@mIbRkkznOkAWztla4JXhBYMjHNAM@opQpoWWoc5hXxNOZ62PCk4qksMeDqGR9PJ1Vo429OB/a7nq7x5QO0GhvlGDKSBK/M21fF3xeEjStDmmWRNZAwJoU20W@2RXy/fyBylz/QsjjJ@wf)

This was my first submission on the site! I got my second Yearling badge today so I thought I'd come back and golf some of my earliest submissions.

Explanation:

```js
f=s=>                     // function f taking string argument s
  (r=                     //   assign variable r to
    s.replace(/./g,c=>    //     s with each character c mapped to:
      Math.random()>.5    //       random true/false
        ?c                //       if true, leave c unchanged
        :c.toUpperCase(a+=2), //   else, uppercase c, and add 2 to a
      a=0                 //     a defaults to 0
    ))                    //   end assignment
  .length-a               //   (length of r) - a
    ?f(s)                 //   if nonzero, start over
    :r                    //   else, return r
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2682) page for ways you can golf your program. As the challenge says that the input will always be of an even length, you don't need to worry about the error

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 142 bytes

```
(defn r[s](let[l(count s)z(apply str(update(vec s)(rand-int l)clojure.string/upper-case))](if(<(count(re-seq #"[A-Z]" z))(/ l 2))(recur z)z)))
```

Un-golfed version:

```
(defn randomly-capitalize-half-of [s]
  (let [v  (vec s)                                 ; convert string s to a vector of characters - e.g. "abcd" becomes [\a \b \c \d]
        l  (count s)                               ; length of string s
        i  (rand-int l)                            ; choose a random index from 0 to (length of s)-1
        v2 (update v i clojure.string/upper-case)  ; convert character at index i in v to upper case
        s2 (apply str v2)                          ; collapse vector-of-characters to a single string
        c  (count (re-seq #"[A-Z]" s2)) ]          ; count number of upper-case letters in s2
    (if (< c (/ l 2))                              ; if count of upper-case letters < 1/2 of length of s
      (recur s2)                                   ;   then recursively invoke randomly-capitalize with partially-upcased string as input
      s2)))                                        ;   else return half-uppercased string
```

Answer (score 0):

## x86_64 machine code, 33 bytes

```
\x89\xf1\x0f\xc7\xf0\x73\xfb\x31\xd2\xf7\xf6\xf6\x04\x17
\x20\x74\xf1\x80\x24\x17\xdf\x83\xe9\x02\x75\xe8\xc3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBBbsIwEDzjV6zSA3ZFqwRooUrpRzCKHNshloIdJU4xRbw9XYcDVQ@Wx7Mzs7uWL0cpx7EohPedKQevi4LSXktvnKXJq9fBJ4wx6L3wRoKsRQdyf4AdSXjYfvBQZTykFQ9ygzjlYbPCu@RhhbxaIo78@/2kax6yTRKtyyhd3@1bxMuphBaM2mKExugU7Zs3xFuMXyX5@GSsbAal4bP3yrjX@ov8pTpjj5Ej/9e59N@FKM1jjW9nFNDnitFpoecFDLY3R6sVgx3InJAnpStjNbQY6mlgoBxcOZlhF9leaLmAwHJ8VxH25ke7KqpeILvT5854HWvZvzI@vXKDn2Tt4OMAdM7tPBI3ONem0UBTRgg2hpMwljK4ktk0aLnP0uX6kKNzmiupddO4s@salbAH2wmr3Km5SNEaLxpsX4umcpW4/9Fx0nbaD52FNCc3Mv4C)

It uses the hardware random generator `rdrand`, which is very slow BTW.

original assembly (nasm)

```
f: ; rdi = string, rsi = number of characters, SysV calling convention
    mov ecx, esi
.loop:
    rdrand eax
    jnc .loop
    xor edx, edx
    div esi
    test byte [rdi + rdx], 0x20
    jz .loop
    and byte [rdi + rdx], 0xdf
    sub ecx, 2
    jnz .loop
    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 103 bytes

```swift
let f={zip($0+"",(0..<$0.count).shuffled().map{$0%2<1}).map{(x,y)in y ?x.uppercased():"\(x)"}.joined()}
```