# Print a cube net of the specified size

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, geometry

### Challenge

Given a size s, print a cube net of that size made of hash symbols (`#`) and spaces ().

Examples:

```
1:
  #
# # #    
  #
  #

2:
    # #
    # #
# # # # # #
# # # # # #
    # #
    # #
    # #
    # #

3:
      # # #
      # # #
      # # #
# # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # #
      # # #
      # # #
      # # #
      # # #
      # # #
      # # #
```

The net can actually be any valid cube net that can fold into a cube, for example these:

```
    # #
    # #
# # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # #
    # #
    # #

    # # # #
    # # # #
    # #
    # #
    # #
    # #
# # # #
# # # #
```

### Rules

- The resulting net must be geometrically valid (foldable into a cube)
- Standard loopholes forbidden
- Read the rules carefully
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins, but will not be selected

Comment: Can there be leading/trailing spaces/newlines?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Yes

Comment: For reference, [all 11 cube nets](http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/math680/cubenets.jpg).

Comment: Is it okay if we output it without the spaces?

Comment: @KritixiLithos no

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19450/enlarge-ascii-art/19457#19457)

Comment: Will the input ever be 0?

Comment: What if I don't read the rules carefully?

Comment: @FlipTack No. It will always be positive as well

Comment: @steenbergh Then your solution is invalid

Answer (score 24):

### Python 2, 47 bytes

```python
n=input()
for c in 1,4,1:exec"print'# '*c*n;"*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59nm5lXUFqiocmVll@kkKyQmadgqGOiY2iVWpGarFRQlJlXoq6soK6VrJVnraSV9/@/MQA)

Prints this net, chosen for being left-justified:

```
# # 
# # 
# # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # 
# # 
# #
```

The lines have `n` or `4*n` copies of `'# '`. For each of `1,4,1`, we print `n` times that many copies, done `n` times for `n` lines. Having an `exec` loop inside a `for` loop seems wasteful, but I didn't see better.

Alternatives I tested:

```python
lambda n:('# '*n*3+'\n')*n+('  '*n+'# '*n+'\n')*3*n

lambda n:('# '*n*3+'\n')*n+(' '*4*n+'# '*n*3+'\n')*n

def f(n):
 for c in[3]*n+[1]*3*n:print('# '*c*n).center(6*n)

def f(n):
 for c in[4]*n+[0]*n:print' '*c*n+'# '*n*3

def f(n):
 for c in[1]*n+[4]*n+[1]*n:print'# '*c*n

def f(n):
 c=1;exec("print'# '*c*n;"*n+"c^=5;"*n)*3

def f(n):
 for i in range(3*n):print'# '*[1,4,1][i/n]*n

def f(n):
 for c in 1,4,1:print('# '*c*n+'\n')*n,

def f(n):
 for c in 1,4,1:exec"print'# '*c*n;"*n
```

(The `def` functions can all be one shorter as a program.)

Answer (score 8):

## Octave, <s>58</s> <s>44</s> <s>42</s> 32 bytes

```
@(n)[z=repmat('# ',n);z,z,z,z;z]
```

partly inspired by @xnor 's python answer.

```
z=repmat('# ',n);
```

creates a squre pattern of '# ' for input 2 results the following pattern:

```
# #             
# # 

y=[z,z,z,z];
```

four `z` s are concatenated horizontally:

```
# # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # 

[z;y;z]
```

`z` and `y` and `z` are concatenated vertically

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#RbANN)

```
# #             
# #             
# # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # 
# #             
# #
```

Previous answer:

```
@(n){h(1:n,1:2:n*6)=1;h(1:n*4,n*2+1:2:4*n)=1;' #'(h+1)}{3}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#imwsv)

Generates a T shaped one

```
# # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # #
      # # #      
      # # #      
      # # #      
      # # #      
      # # #      
      # # #      
      # # #      
      # # #      
      # # #
```

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, <s>77</s> <s>60</s> 52 bytes

*Thanks to Martin Ender for golfing 8 bytes away!*

```
{±s_:=s~Table~#;b=±{a=±"# ","
"},±{a,a,a,a,"
"}}<>b&
```

Unnamed function taking a positive integer argument `#` and returning a string with newlines (including a trailing newline); each line has a trailing space as well. First we define `±` to be a function that repeats its input `#` times; then `a` is defined as `±"# "` (this `#` is a character, not the input!), and from that `b` is defined to be the set of `#` short lines, while `±{a,a,a,a}<>n` is the set of `#` long lines. (In both cases, there is a literal linefeed between matching quotes.) The final `<>b` concatenates the resulting list of strings with second copy of the set of short lines. Example output when `#=2` ([xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106824/56178) taught me that this orientation is golfier):

```
# #     
# #     
# # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # 
# #     
# #
```

Previous version of this implementation:

```
""<>(±s_:=s&~Array~#;{b=±{a=±"# ",n="\n"},±{a,a,a,a}<>n,b})&
```

Original submission:

```
""<>If[(m=n~Mod~t)==0,"\n",If[n<t#||#<m<=2#,"# ","  "]]~Table~{n,4(t=3#+1)#}&
```

Builds a string out of `4*(3#+1)` pieces, each of which is either `"# "`, `"  "`, or `"\n"`; simply calculates which pieces to use based on the index `n`. Example output when `#=2`:

```
# # # # # # 
# # # # # # 
    # #     
    # #     
    # #     
    # #     
    # #     
    # #
```

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 59 bytes

```js
f=
n=>`141`.replace(/./g,m=>`${`# `.repeat(n*m)}\n`.repeat(n))
```

```html
<input type=number oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Output includes a trailing space at the end of each line and a trailing newline.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 36 bytes

```
f=->n{puts (t=[s="# "*n]*n)+[s*4]*n+t}
```

Usage:

```
f=->n{puts (t=[s="# "*n]*n)+[s*4]*n+t}
f[3]
# # #
# # #
# # #
# # # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # # #
# # #
# # #
# # #
```

## Ruby, 38 bytes

This shape is longer in Ruby but I expect there are some languages where it is shorter.

```
->n{puts [s="# "*n*3]*n+[" "*n*4+s]*n}
```

Usage:

```
g=->n{puts [s="# "*n*3]*n+[" "*n*4+s]*n}
g[3]
# # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # #
            # # # # # # # # #
            # # # # # # # # #
            # # # # # # # # #
```

Both answers can be shorter if it is permitted to return (preferably) an array of strings or (less preferably) a single string instead of printing.

Comment: Returning a string is considered a valid form of output.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 71

```
n=>((z='# '[R='repeat'](n))[R](3)+`
`)[R](n)+('  '[R](n)+z+`
`)[R](n*3)
```

**Test**

```js
f=
n=>((z='# '[R='repeat'](n))[R](3)+`
`)[R](n)+('  '[R](n)+z+`
`)[R](n*3)

function update() {
  O.textContent=f(I.value)
}

update()
```

```html
<input id=I type=number value=3 oninput='update()'><pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think you need to output the spaces along with the hashes. (I also made that mistake of not including the spaces in the first edit of my answer)

Comment: @KritixiLithos uh, got it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>20</s> <s>18</s> 20 bytes

```
Ài# ddÀpLyGïp3PGïp
```

With all the hidden characters shown

```
Ài# ^[ddÀp^VLyGïp3PGoïp
```

`^[` is `0x1b` (escape character literal) and `^V` is `0x16` (`C-v`)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3@4IVNZQTol5XBDgZhPpfvh9QXGASDy////RgA)

I had to increase bytecount because the `Ä` command was being buggy in this new V pull

Outputs in this format:

```
# 
# # # # 
#
```

with a leading newline

Hexdump:

```
00000000: c069 2320 1b64 64c0 7016 4c79 47ef 7033  .i# .dd.p.LyG.p3
00000010: 5047 ef70                                PG.p
```

### Explanation

```
Ài# ^[              " Argument times insert "# "
ddÀp                " Argument times duplicate line
```

Now that one face of the net has been completed, we have to create the net

```
^VLy                " Copy the face
Gïp                 " Paste it at the end of buffer
3P                  " Paste 3 times (these form the line)
Gïp                 " Paste at end of buffer again
```

---

Alternate solution if we don't output the spaces:

#### <s>21</s> <s>20</s> <s>18</s> <s>16</s> 18 bytes

```
Àé#ddÀpLyGïp3pGïp
```

(for the same reason as the top solution, this TIO link is modified)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3@44fBK5ZSUww0FYj6V7ofXFxgHgMj///8bAgA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
”#xẋ³Wẋ³K€Y
141DÇ€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYa5yxcNd3Yc2h4NJ70dNayK5DE0MXQ63g5j///83NAAA)

*-1 thanks to 44874 (steenbergh).*

<sup>I CAN'T OUTGOLF MUDDYFISH HELP!</sup>

Is this golfable??? <s>20</s> 19 bytes just seems like **too much**, seeing Link 1.

Explanation:

```
”#xẋ³Wẋ³K€Y Helper link. Arguments: z
”#          Character #.
            y (implicit)
  x         Repeat each element of y x times.
    ³       1st command-line argument.
   ẋ        Repeat x y times.
     W      Wrap z.
       ³    1st command-line argument.
      ẋ     Repeat x y times.
        K   Join z on spaces.
         €  Map this link on x.
          Y Join z on newlines.

141DÇ€Y Main link. Arguments: 0
141     Integer 141.
   D    Convert z to base 10.
    Ç   The above link as a monad.
     €  Map this link on x.
      Y Join z on newlines.
```

Comment: It's V versus Jelly now :)

Comment: @KritixiLithos Nah, your solution was first.

Comment: V is at 18 bytes now :)

Comment: You can drop a byte by not using `@` but swapping the operands to `x` yourself: `”#xẋ³Wẋ³K€Y`.

Answer (score 4):

## Scala, 56 bytes

```
(n:Int)=>Seq(1,4,1)map("# "*_*n+"\n")map(_*n)mkString ""
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, 99 bytes

```
l->{for(int i=-1,j;++i<3*l;)for(j=-1,k=(i/l==2)?4*l:l;++j<k;)System.out.print("# "+j>k-2?"\n":"");}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 14 bytes (non-competing)

```
Ài# 5Ù4JjòÀÄk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3@4IVNZQdr08EwTr6zDmw43HG7J/v//vwkA)

```
00000000: c069 2320 1b35 d934 4a6a f2c0 c46b       .i# .5.4Jj...k
```

For whatever reason, this challenge uncovered numerous bugs. Now that they're all fixed, this version is unfortunately non-competing, but it's nice to see what a V answer to this challenge should look like when it doesn't have to add tons of bytes to keep up with my sloppy coding.

Explanation:

```
À                   " Arg 1 times:
 i# <esc>           "   Insert the string "# "
         5Ù         " Make 5 copies of this line, and put the cursor on the second copy
           4J       " Join four of these lines together
             j      " Move down to the last line
              ò     " Recursively:
               ÀÄ   "   Make Arg 1 copies of this line
                 k  "   And move up a line
```

Comment: To be fair, the `J` issue wasn't sloppy coding AFAIK, I think it was just nvim default?

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But the duplicate operator definitely was sloppy. Thankfully this new version is much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
ＮλＧ↑λ←×⁶λ↓λ# ＤＭ×⁴λ←
```

The code ends with a space. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/9@z7pzu9/vWf6obeK53Y/aJhye/qhxG4g1@dxuZYX3e5a837MWJLYFLKvw/78xAA)

#### Explanation

Charcoal is a language specializing in ASCII art. It is also incomplete, buggy, and under-documented. Suffice it to say, this took a fair amount of trial and error before it did what it was supposed to.

- `Ｎλ` inputs a number into `λ`.
- `Ｇ` is the polygon command, which we'll use here to draw a rectangle. `↑λ←×⁶λ↓λ` specifies the border of the polygon: upward `λ` steps, leftward 6 times `λ` steps, and downward `λ` steps. (That's three `λ` by `λ` blocks side-by-side.) The bottom edge of the rectangle is inferred. The polygon is then filled with the string `#` .
- `Ｄ` dumps the current canvas to stdout, resulting in something like this:

```
 # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # #
```

- After the `Ｇ` command, the cursor is at the bottom left corner of the canvas. `Ｍ×⁴λ←` moves it leftward by 4 times `λ` steps (equivalent to two `λ` by `λ` blocks).
- outputs a space there, extending the canvas leftward by the correct amount.
- At the end of the program, the canvas is (again) sent to stdout:

```
             # # # # # # # # #
             # # # # # # # # #
             # # # # # # # # #
```

Put 'em together and you've got a cube net.

Comment: Wow, you really had to struggle back then! (Oblong wasn't added until several weeks later.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>68</s> <s>71</s> 65 bytes

-6 with thanks to @sagiksp

```python
def f(i,c=1):
 print(' '*i*4,'')[c>i]+'# '*i*3
 if i*2>c:f(i,c+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@SmqaQppGpk2xrqGnFpVBQlJlXoqGuoK6VqWWio66uGZ1slxmrra4MFjHmUshMU8jUMrJLtgJr0jbU/J@mYar5HwA)

In the absence of finding a way to beat @xnor I'll post my recursive function simply as an alternative approach. For f(5) prints

```python
                    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
                    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
                    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
                    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
                    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

This pattern was chosen simply because it can be split into two parts unlike all of the others.

Comment: Where are the spaces?

Comment: Without the spaces in the output, this isn't valid.

Comment: My mistake +3 to add the spaces. Updated.

Comment: Actually why do you even need j? You can redefine the entire thing in terms of i and save ~6 bytes!

Comment: @sagiksp - Thanks. Updated using your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) / Unix utilities, <s>72</s> <s>69</s> <s>68</s> 66 bytes

```bash
b()(yes `dc<<<2o4d$n^$1^3/p`|tr 01 ' #'|head -$n);n=$1;b 1;b 4;b 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@koalRmVqskJCSbGNjY5RvkqKSF6diGGesX5BQU1KkYGCooK6grF6TkZqYoqCrkqdpnWerYmidpADCJiD6////xgA)

This works by using the fact that [4^k / 3], when written in base 2, is 10101010...01, with k 1's. (The square brackets here denote the floor function.)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyke, 16 bytes

```
uAD,sXF**"#
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=u%03%01%04%01AD%2CsXF%2a%2a%22%23+&input=2&warnings=0)

Equivalent to

```
1 4 1]3AD,sXF**"#
```

Because of unprintables

This uses a couple of tricks to lower the byte-count:

- It uses some unprintables to represent the list `[1, 4, 1]`
- `XF` automatically dumps the output to the stack
- The string `"#`  at the end gets swapped with the last `*`, meaning that the closing `"` is not required. This happens implicitly when the last token is a string.

```
u                -      [1, 4, 1]
     AD          -     apply(*, ^, input)
       ,         -    zip(^)
        s        -   sum(^)
          F**"#  -  for i in ^:
           *     -    ^ * input
            *    -   ^ * v
             "#  -    "# "
         X       - splat(^)
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <strike>64</strike> 62 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Christoph](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29637/christoph).

```
while($a="282"[$i++/$s=$argv[1]]*$s)echo str_pad("
",$a,"# ");
```

Prints a net like this:

```
# #
# #
# # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # #
# #
# #
```

(with a leading newline)

Comment: `while($a="282"[$i++/$s=$argv[1]]*$s)echo str_pad("\n",$a,"# ");` saves 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 111 bytes

```
@set s=
@set i=@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @
%i%call set s=%%s%% #
%i%echo%s%
%i%echo%s%%s%%s%%s%
%i%echo%s%
```

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>52</s> <s>67</s> 40 bytes

Complete re-write:

```
:[a*3|G=G+@#`][a*2|G=G+@ `][a|?G][a|?_fG
```

This now uses this pattern:

```
###--
--###
```

Where the `-`are filled with spaces.

```
:        Read 'a' from the command line        > Assume 3
[a*3|    Create 3 segments times 'a' filling   > 3*3 = 9
G=G+@#`] Define A$ to be '#' and add this to G > G = "#########" 
[a*2|    Create 2 segments times 'a' spacer
G=G+@ `] Define B$ to be ' ' and add this to G > G = "#########       " 
[a|      FOR d == 1; d <= a; d++
?G]      Display G$:
            "#########       " 
            "#########       " 
            "#########       " 
[a|      FOR e == 1; e <= a; e++
?_fG     Display G$ in reverse (_f...|):
            "      #########" 
            "      #########" 
            "      #########" 
         (For loop and function call to Flip impicitly closed by QBIC)
```

Comment: [This answer is invalid, per this comment by OP.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/106820/print-a-cube-net-of-the-specified-size/106828?noredirect=1#comment259788_106820)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Updated.

Comment: Appropriate language name for the challenge!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), <s>32</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

Prints the cube net left-justified. This was hard to golf...

```
&V:`# `;{:";N^:4:";T'.;TD^:"
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@68WZpWgrJBgXW2lZO0XZ2UCpELU9axDXOKslP7//28CAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <strike>39</strike> 37 bytes

This is my first time using Retina, I'm still trying to understand how to do things.

```
.+
$*#
#
# 
\`# 
$_¶
G`.
)*%`^
$_$_$_
```

(with two trailing spaces after the 4th and 5th lines)

Thanks to Martin Ender for golfing 2 bytes!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@nzaWipcwFhApcMQlAQiX@0DYu9wQ9Lk0t1YQ4IBcE//83AgA)

Comment: @MartinEnder Thank you, I had not noticed that requirement, now it should be correct. Do you have any suggestion to how I should try to golf this?

Comment: Not having a lot of brilliant ideas but https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@nzaWipcwFhApcMQlAQiX@0DYu9wQ9Lk0t1YQ4IBcE//83AgA saves two bytes. You can avoid the trailing linefeeds by wrapping everything in a group which has its output flag (and since the group is the last thing the program, the output flag defaults to being non-silent). The other byte avoids the fourth `$_` at the bottom by switching some things around after removing the empty line. https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@nzaWipcwFhApcMQlAQiX@0DYuzRgt1QQ9FS4FlXgQPLTt/38jAA is the same byte count but a bit uglier.

Comment: @MartinEnder Thank you for the tips, and thank you for this language too, it's really nice!

Comment: Thank you for the kind words. :) [There's a chatroom for it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41525/retina) if you have any questions or want to discuss things. It's currently rather quiet, but I try to keep it unfrozen in case people have questions (and you should be able to ping me in there any time).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>28</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

15 bytes of code, +1 for `-n` flag.

```
"# "Xa*_RLaM141
```

Takes the size as a command-line argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@6@krKAUkagVH@ST6GtoYvj//3/dvP/GAA)

#### Explanation

```
                 a is 1st cmdline arg
       _         Build a lambda function
     a*          (a) times argument
"# "X            Repeat string "# " that many times
        RLa      Wrap in a list and repeat list (a) times
           M141  Map that function to the characters of 141
                 Autoprint (-n flag separating list items with newlines)
```

The following isn't exactly how the data gets modified, but it gives the basic idea (for `a=2`):

```
141

[1;4;1]

[2;8;2]

["# # ";"# # # # # # # # ";"# # "]

[["# # ";"# # "];["# # # # # # # # ";"# # # # # # # # "];["# # ";"# # "]]

# # 
# # 
# # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # 
# # 
# #
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
D141S×S*„# ×»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@9iaGIYfHh6sNajhnnKCoenH9r9/78xAA)

**Explanation**

Example input `n=2`

```
D              # duplicate input
               # STACK: 2, 2
 141S          # push the list [1,4,1]
               # STACK: 2, 2, [1,4,1]
     ×         # repeat each item in the list input_no times
               # STACK: 2, [11, 44, 11]
      S        # split into list of digits
               # STACK: 2, [1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1]
       *       # multiply each digit with input
               # STACK: [2, 2, 8, 8, 2, 2]
        „# ×   # repeat the string "# " for each item in the list
               # STACK: ['# # ','# # ','# # # # # # # # ','# # # # # # # # ','# # ','# # ']
            »  # join by newlines
               # OUTPUT: # # 
                         # # 
                         # # # # # # # # 
                         # # # # # # # # 
                         # # 
                         # #
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, <s>57</s> 50 bytes

```
INPUT S
E$=("#"*S*3+CHR$(10))*S?E$SCROLL-S*2,-1?E$
```

Explained:

```
INPUT SIZE
PART$=("#"*SIZE*3+CHR$(10))*S 'generate half of the pattern
PRINT PART$ 'print half the pattern
SCROLL SIZE*-2,-1 'scroll the text 2 squares right (and 1 character down)
PRINT PART$ 'print half the pattern again
```

After the first PRINT (size=2, @ is the cursor position):

```
######
######

@
```

After the SCROLL:

```
    ######
    ######
@
```

After the second PRINT:

```
    ######
    ######
######
######
@
```

Comment: In this case you can skip the spaces

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 152 bytes

```
n=>{var m="";foreach(int c in new[]{1,4,1})for(int i=0,j;i++<n;){for(j=0;j++<c;)m+=new System.Text.StringBuilder().Insert(0,"# ",n);m+="\n";}return m;};
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, <s>83</s> <s>81</s> 79 bytes

```
(lambda(x)(format t"~v@{~v@{# ~}~:*~%~}~v@{~vt~0@*~v{# ~}~%~}"x(* x 3)(* x 2)))
```

Usage:

`(funcall #'(lambda(x)(format t"~v@{~v@{# ~}~:*~%~}~v@{~vt~0@*~v{# ~}~%~}"x(* x 3)(* x 2)))2)`

Output:

```
# # # # # #
# # # # # #
    # # 
    # # 
    # # 
    # #       
    # # 
    # #
```

#### How does it work?

```
in format there is control string (inside "") and arguments after it
certain commands in string can use arguments (for example ~a displays argument)
~v{~} - takes argument and does commends inside {~} number of times 
                                      (number is given by argument)
       we can write text in loop body - it'll get displayed. Even if
       in loop body there are none commends to use arguments loop itself                 
       will consume one argument (it doesn't matter what it'll be -
       it doesn't seem to affect output)
~% - newline
~n* - jump n arguments forward (relative)
~n:* - jump n arguments backwards (relative)
~n@* - jump to argument n (global, counting from 0)

~v@{~v{# ~}~%~1@*~} <--- we make x rowns, 3x columns of string "# ". 
                         ~1@* is used during looping, it also means we end on argument 1. 
                         (second argument: (* x 3))
~v@{~vt~0@*~v{# ~}~%~} <--- we now make 3x rows, x columns of "(spaces)# "
                         ~vt - is used to move to accurate column. 
                         Here it takes argument (* x 2) - this is 
                         minimal number of columns to display. It uses
                         space as default character for missing characters
                         (when string inside <~> is shorter than min 
                         number of columns). I use it to make (* x 2) spaces, 
                         by giving it no text.
      ~0@* <--- after making spaces we have no new arguments, we go back to
                argument number zero - it is used to determine number of columns in our block
```

Ideas for improvement are welcomed.