# My device malfunctions... Abuse its undefined string behaviour!

Tags: code-golf, string

Help! My device malfunctions and whenever I try to repeat a String, I get a messy results. Instead of repeating the same string **N** times, it fills an **NxN** square with each of its characters, and stacks the squares up.

For example, given the String `"Test"` and the number `2`, instead of `"TestTest"`, I get:

```
TT
TT
ee
ee
ss
ss
tt
tt
```

---

After I have seen this for a while, I started to like it. Your task today is to reproduce this strange behaviour. Given a *non-empty* string that consists of printable ASCII only, and a *positive* integer, output the String my malfunctioning device returns.

- All standard rules apply.
- The input and output may be handled through any reasonable mean.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes in each language wins.

---

## Test Cases

```
Input 
Output

----------

"Test", 2

TT
TT
ee
ee
ss
ss
tt
tt

----------

"UuU", 3

UUU
UUU
UUU
uuu
uuu
uuu
UUU
UUU
UUU

----------

"A", 5

AAAAA
AAAAA
AAAAA
AAAAA
AAAAA

----------
```

You can [find a larger test case here](https://pastebin.com/HJRQ986T). Good luck and have fun golfing!

Comment: Borderline duplicate of [Enlarge ASCII art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19450/enlarge-ascii-art)

Comment: Is a "list of lines" instead of a string separated by newlines valid?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how the "abuse its undefined behavior" from the title actually shows in the task. There is no undefined behavior, the task is to reproduce a quite specifically defined behavior.

Comment: `it fills an NxN square` - Not a correct statement.

Comment: Vyxal, 1 byte: `*` Only works on your machine.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

This is exactly what we are asked to do... Abuse undefined behaviour!*

```
×+⁷×⁴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wdO1HjdsPT3/UuOX///@OTs4urv@NAQ)

<sup>* By *undefined behaviour* I am talking about using `×` for repeating strings. Sometimes it's shorter than usual behaviour, so why not?</sup>

Comment: Damn, beat me by a minute!

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I have a feeling it can be golfed, though :-/

Comment: I have used your abuse to [golf a different five byter down to four](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141809/53748)

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Inspired by [Mr. Xcoder's Jelly abuse](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141703/53748)

```
x⁹×Y
```

A full program taking the string and the number as command line arguments and printing the result (since as a dyadic link it returns a list of strings and newline characters, which may not really be acceptable).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/iUePOw9Mj////7@7v4/bfFAA)**

#### How?

The naive (non-abusive) five byter is:

```
x⁹x€Y - Main link: list of characters, s; number, n  e.g. "xyz", 2
 ⁹    - chain's right argument, n                         2
x     - times (repeat each element)                       ['x','x','y','y','z','z']
  x€  - times for €ach                                   [['x','x'],['x','x'],['y','y'],['y','y'],['z','z'],['z','z']]
    Y - join with newlines                                ['x','x','\n','x','x','\n','y','y','\n','y','y','\n','z','z','\n','z','z']
      - as a full program: implicit print
      -   note: this could be submitted as a dyadic link (AKA unnamed function)
```

The abuse used by Mr. Xcoder (Python's `operator.mul` may act on a `str` and an `int` to repeat the `str` - here single characters - and the atom which uses it, `×`, vectorises w.r.t. its left argument) can be used here too to replace `x€` with `×` - yielding the full program:

```
x⁹×Y - Main link: list of characters, s; number, n  e.g. "xyz", 2
 ⁹   - chain's right argument, n                         2
x    - times (repeat each element)                       ['x','x','y','y','z','z']
  ×  - multiply (vectorises)                             ["xx","xx","yy","yy","zz","zz"]
     -     (note, these "..." are actually strings, something not usually seen in Jelly) 
    Y - join with newlines                                ["xx",'\n',"xx",'\n',"yy",'\n',"yy",'\n',"zz",'\n',"zz"]
      - implicit print
```

Comment: heh abuse on challenge about abuse

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 26 bytes

The function `(!)` returns a list of lines.

```hs
n!s=map(<$[1..n])s<*[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0@x2DY3sUDDRiXaUE8vL1az2EYLwvqfm5iZp2CrUFBaElxS5JOnoFGal5OZl1qsoKGhqKlgpKAUklpcoqSpyaUABHZ2uBQaKyiFloYSVmeqoOQIVPUfAA)

Answer (score 5):

## Bash + GNU Sed, 58

Using a very similar technique to [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19457/11259) to illustrate how close to being a dup to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19450/enlarge-ascii-art) that this question is:

```bash
printf -vr %$1s
sed "s/./${r// /&}\n/g;s/\S*./${r// /&}/g"
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUG3rEhBVcWwmKs4NUVBqVhfT1@lukhfX0FfrTYmTz/dulg/JlgLSVA/Xen//5DU4pL/xgA).

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @Zgarb

```
SṀRṘ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/jhzoaghztn/P//3@h/SGpxCQA)

Comment: `ṠMRṘ` works if you swap the inputs.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [scottinet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73296/scottinet)

```
ε×²F=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3NbD0w9tcrP9/z@0NJTLGAA)

```
ε     # For each character:
 ×    #   Repeat this character N times
  ²F  #   For 0 .. N:
    = #     Print without popping
```

Comment: -2 bytes by taking advantage of implicit inputs, printing without popping (`=`) and by replacing `vy`with `ε` : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3NbD0w9tcrP9/z@0NJTLGAA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: I know this answer is almost 6 years old, but you can [save a byte](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8PTgw9MP7f7/P1opRElHKRWIi4G4RCmWyxgA) by taking the input-string as a list of characters.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 31 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)$a|%{,("$_"*$b)*$b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRRyVJUyWxRrVaR0NJJV5JC8gF4tr///9rRCdnJBZFx8aqh5aGqmv@NwYA)

Explanation:

```powershell
param($a,$b)                    # Takes input $a (char-array) and $b (integer)
            $a|%{             } # Loop through every character in $a
                   "$_"*$b      # Construct a string of $b length of that character
                 ,(       )*$b  # Repeat that $b times
                                # Implicit Write-Output inserts a newline between elements
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:"".join(y*(r*y+"\n")for r in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1BCsIwEEXX9hTDrJIaurC4CXThHezKikSbYKRNShKhQTx7TARxMTDDf2/@EsPdmjapbkiTmK@jgJVFjtg8rDYk1sTVcYuDQaqsAwfawEpTkD5cbsJLDx2cCB7zjWxHGcH@2SNry3ZAtqfnqnj5ZzH/Gq82i9MmEHzxN@Th2GRwFoFkljJpxi63lt4fqb4JTR8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 7 bytes

Outputs an array of strings.

```
VÆmpVÃy
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=VsZtcFbDeQ==&input=IlRlc3QiCjIKLVI=) (`-R` flag for visualisation purposes only)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of string `U` and integer `V`.

```
VÆ    Ã
```

Generate an array of integers from `0` to `V-1` and pass each through a function.

```
mpV
```

Map (`m`) over `U` and repeat (`r`) each character `V` times.

```
y
```

Transpose and implicitly output resulting array.

Answer (score 2):

### C++, <s>125</s> 123 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to aschepler

```cpp
#include<string>
using s=std::string;s u(s a,int b){s r;for(auto&c:a)for(int i=0;i<b*b;){if(!(i++%b))r+=10;r+=c;}return r;}
```

Make sure that the overload of the `+=` operator called takes a `char` data type in this instruction `if(!(i++%b))r+=10`

Comment: `using s=std::string;` is shorter than `typedef std::string s;` by two bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
t&Y"!
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v0QtUknx/38jLvWQ1OISdQA)

#### Explanation

```
t     % Implicitly input a number, n. Duplicate
&Y"   % Implicitly input a string. Three-input repelem function. Repeats
      % each entry in the first input (s) the specified numbers of times 
      % vertically (n) and horizontally (n). Gives a char matrix
!     % Transpose. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

-1 thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

```
ＦＳ«ＧTηι↓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLQkuKQoMy9dQ1NToZpLAQgC8nMq0/PzNKxCdBQydBQyNa3Bwr75ZakaVi755XlAgdr//0NSi0v0FMz@65b91y3O@a@bCAA)

### Explanation

```
ＦＳ        For each character (i) in the next input as a string
   «
    Ｇ   ι  Polygon using i as fill
      T     Right, down, then left
       η    The second input (h) (automatically casted to a number)
          ↓ Move down
```

Comment: I know this answer is nearly 6 years old, but you no longer need the cast and can change `Ｉη`/`Cast(h)` to `η`/`h`.

Comment: smh necroposting lol

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck, 103 Bytes

```
,[>,]-[>+<-----]>---[-<<->>]<<[->+<]>[[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<[<<<[<]>.[>]>>-]++++++++++.[-]<<<[<]>[-]>[>]>
```

[Try it online](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=LFs-LF08IFRha2UgSW5wdXQKPi1bPis8LS0tLS1dPi0tLSBBU0NJSSAwLCB0byB1c2UgaW4gbmV4dCBzdGVwClstPDwtPj5dPDwgQ29udmVydCBBU0NJSSBudW1iZXIgdG8gcmF3IG51bWJlciBieSBzdWJ0cmFjdGluZyBBU0NJSSAwClstPis8XT4gTW92ZSB0aGUgbnVtYmVyIG92ZXIgb25lIHRvIHNlcGFyYXRlIGl0IGZyb20gdGhlIHBocmFzZQpbCiAgWy0-Kz4rPDxdPj5bLTw8Kz4-XTwgQ29weSB0aGUgbnVtYmVyCiAgWwogICAgPDw8WzxdPiBCYWNrIHRvIExldHRlcgogICAgLiBQcmludCBMZXR0ZXIKICAgIFs-XT4-LSBCYWNrIHRvIENvdW50ZXIKICBdCiAgKysrKysrKysrKy5bLV08IFByaW50IHRoZSBuZXdsaW5lCiAgPDxbPF0-Wy1dPiBDbGVhciBMZXR0ZXIKICBbPl0-IEJhY2sgdG8gQ291bnRlcgpd) (Make sure to turn on dynamic memory or it won't run)

Note: The input is slightly different. This code takes in a string where the last character is a digit for number of repeats. So input might look like `Test5`.

This code requires an unbounded tape, and relies on byte wrapping behavior.

Ungolfed:

```
,[>,]< Take Input
>-[>+<-----]>--- ASCII 0, to use in next step
[-<<->>]<< Convert ASCII number to raw number by subtracting ASCII 0
[->+<]> Move the number over one to separate it from the phrase
[
  [->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]< Copy the number
  [
    <<<[<]> Back to Letter
    . Print Letter
    [>]>>- Back to Counter
  ]
  ++++++++++.[-]< Print the newline
  <<[<]>[-]> Clear Letter
  [>]> Back to Counter
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, <sub><s>15</s></sub> 14 bytes

```
[:,/]$"1 0~[,[
```

Sub-optimal for sure. Returns a 2D array of chars. Takes `n` as the left argument and the string as the right.

On mobile, so the usual amenities are missing.

## Explanation

(For old answer)

```
[:,/(2#[)$"1 0]
```

`$"1 0` reshape each character to

`(2#[)` an `n` * `n` matrix.

`,/` join matrices together to yield the output.

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYy7CsJAEEX7/YqLEUZBxAc2goWWFlamslqWWbMhJDCzKfz6dWO2srrnnnm0KXlcznhV1WJnDLtmwAEe9GSNNHcqeZx8PdZ/@pT1HkvQlYx53LYTIETlziMo2lEjLFxjZQONEvq3IvS4wwr/dAaxH83TAavyaQ0nbCNrOZ13UvoC)

Comment: @miles brilliant! I'd say that deserves its own answer personally.

Comment: @miles post yours :)

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGLOnline commit 2940dbe](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline/tree/2940dbe13bc955f6456c1d3a737b40e255a1d103), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
∙ι*I
```

This was made for a specific commit, namely the one before I changed `∙` from, when used on an array of strings, repeating each letter x times to repeat each item x times. [Here](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyMjE5JXUwM0I5Kkk_,inputs=VGVzdCUwQTM_) is the online interpreter without that version, which, as can be seen, doesn't work.

To try the commit, download [this](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline/tree/2940dbe13bc955f6456c1d3a737b40e255a1d103), open the `index.html` file, in the program paste `∙ι*I` and in the input write something like

```
Test
2
```

Explanation:

```
∙ι*I
∙     get an array with 2nd input amount of items of the 1st input
 ι    pop one implicit input to cycle back to the number
  *   multiply horizontally each separate character
   I  rotate clockwise
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, why the link?

Comment: @isaacg good question. First I intended it to write what changed, but forgot

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 59 bytes

```r
function(S,n)write(rep(strsplit(S,"")[[1]],e=n*n),"",n,,"")
```

Writes to stdout.

Splits the string into characters, repeats each `n^2` times, and then prints with width `n` and with no separator.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcgxCoAwDADAr0imROKgs75Ct9JJUihILGnE59c63llLwzq19Ojp@VbcWem17IImBatbLVf23gAUwhwjy6ajUjcr/9sSwiHVgRdqHw)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
VEp*+*NQb
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VEp%2a%2B%2aNQb&input=%22Test%22%0A2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A%22Test%22%0A3%0A%22UuU%22%0A5%0A%22A%22%0A25%0A%22ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%22&debug=0&input_size=2)

## Pyth, <s><sub>11</sub></s> 10 bytes

```
sm*Q+*QdbE
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%2aQ%2B%2aQdbE&input=3%0A%22ABCDE%22&debug=0)

**Or, 10 bytes:**

```
jsm*Q]*QdE
```

**Or, 11 bytes:**

```
js*RQm]*dQE
jsm*vzm*dvz
sm*vz+*dvzb
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 26 + 1 (-p) = 27 bytes

```perl
$"=<>;s|.|($&x$".$/)x$"|ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FydbGzrq4Rq9GQ0WtQkVJT0VfE0jVpKf@/@@en5@ikJhWklqUl5@fp6MQnl@Uk6LIZf4vv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megaHBf90CAA)

Comment: This seems to replace each character with a horizontal row of characters, not with a square of characters.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand it properly at first.  Fixed it with an extra 5 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>152</s> <s>128</s> <s>118</s> 100 bytes

```
s->n->{for(char c:s)for(int j=0;j++<n;System.out.println("".valueOf(new char[n]).replace('\0',c)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZCxbsMgFEV3fwXy0EBtozQriaUqUqUOVYd0Sz1Qgh0ofiDAqaIo3@7i1EOl9m1cBOe8q/mJV9ZJ0IfPUfXO@oh0yugQlaHtACIqC/SeZZkbPowSSBgeAnrhCtAlQ2lC5DHlWwth6KVfP0OUnfQ1ajdQ1ZfWeqwgIrVZMrUGtjuHKHtqh0idTxcGMNBodzEdOlwU6q5S5YpQI6GLR0yqB0LYNfF/sZ5mr7U4cr9vyr/wGnVog8ZQ1ZPDzC81m2ySRpi/Z6ooyJTpZKeTnS6K8h/DPKcnbgb52mKQX@iGhYZQL53hQuLF@3JRhr1qyCQ7zrZzY7P0yaoD6lNv@GfXfYO47wKZa5ymo9w5c8b5mwwxT61sE@jRe37GhFAuhHQRrwi7Pbhm1/Eb)

Comment: 100 bytes: `s->n->{for(char c:s)for(int j=0;j++<n;System.out.println("".valueOf(new char[n]).replace('\0',c)));}`

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes

Takes repetition as left argument and text as right argument.

```apl
{⍺⌿⍺/⍪⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3zGptDj1UduE6ke9ux717AeS@o96Vz3q3Vr7/7@RAlhWQT0ktbhEncsYxg0tDVXnMoXxHNUB)

`{`…`}` an unnamed lambda where `⍺` represents the left argument and `⍵` the right argument

`⍪⍵` make the text into a one-column table

`⍺/` replicate `⍺` times horizontally

`⍺⌿` replicate `⍺` times vertically

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
mpV² òV
```

Returns an array of strings.

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=bXBWsiDyVg==&input=IlRlc3QiCjIKLVI=) with the `-R` flag to join the array with newlines.

### Explanation

```
mpV² òV     Implicit input of U=string, V=number
m           Map each char in the input string to...
 pV²        Itself repeated V² times
     òV     Cut the resulting string into partitions of length V
```

Answer (score 1):

## D, 86 bytes

```d
S u(S,I)(S a,I b){S r;foreach(c;a)for(I i;i<b*b;){if(!(i++%b))r~='\n';r~=c;}return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYuxDoIwEEB3vuIkMdwJcXA9/QDmOrq0UOIl0pqj6EDw12uHl/eWN@ZsYEXT9YQGbNeDo82A8hTV2@GJA1sqjT0Iy9WdHNMmEx5Q2vboiPR3ax6h4eKBd/Vp1VD2vfpEGWG2EpBgq2R@R02wpPFckMhfleRfAVes735JdXch4mrP@Q8)

Takes the string as the left argument, and the integer as the right argument.
This is a port of [HatsuPointerKun's C++ answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141724/55550) into D.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ḅd×
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCU4NGQlQzMlOTcmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0yJTBBJTIyVGVzdCUyMiZmbGFncz1O)

Takes the number then the string

##### Explanation

```python
Ḅd×  # Implicit input                                  ->  2, "Test"
Ḅ    # Multiply each of the characters by the number   ->  "TTeesstt"
 d   # Split this string into a list of characters     ->  ["T",  "T",  "e",  "e",  "s",  "s",  "t",  "t" ]
  ×  # Repeat each character input number of times     ->  ["TT", "TT", "ee", "ee", "ss", "ss", "tt", "tt"]
     # Implicit output, joined on newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>83</s> 79 bytes

```c
i,j;f(p,n)char*p,n;{for(;*p;p++)for(i=n;i--;puts(""))for(j=n;j--;putchar(*p));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcsxDsIwDIXh3aeoMtlpspTR4hZcIIpISUSD1ZSp6tUxKbzp1ye96OcYVbMrnFBcpfgIq@3Be3qtyFZYxpHOztfK2XuW99bQGPph6Vj@eD7RChEfuoRckWCHoS@hud3bZtwwEcMBoJ@YnmFu6pfL9AU)

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 11 Bytes

```
{__*@e*/N*}
```

Function that takes string followed by int.

[Try it Online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=lli%7B__*%40e*%2FN*%7D~&input=abcd%0A5)

Answer (score 0):

## Kotlin 1.1 - 99 bytes

```
fun s(s:String,c:Int)=s.flatMap{p->List(c,{p})}.joinToString("\n"){p->List(c,{p}).joinToString("")}
```

Returns the whole output as a string.

**Can't use TryItOnline as 1.1 is not supported**

### Test

```
fun s(s:String,c:Int)=s.flatMap{p->List(c,{p})}.joinToString("\n"){p->List(c,{p}).joinToString("")}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(s("Hello World", 5))
}
```

It would be 84 if a list of strings was acceptable as output:

```
fun s(s:String,c:Int)=s.flatMap{p->List(c,{p})}.map{p->List(c,{p}).joinToString("")}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 49 bytes

```
(z=#2;Grid[Column/@Table[#,z,z]&/@Characters@#])&
```

**input**

> ["Test",4]

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 97 bytes

```
for($i=0;$i<strlen($s=$argv[1]);$i++)for($j=0;$j<$r=$argv[2];$j++)echo str_repeat($s[$i],$r)."
";
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

Small minded, but I haven't gotten there just yet.

```
VQp*+*Nszbsz
```

Explanation:

```
VQ          For every letter in the first input...
  p         Print without newline...
   *+*Nszsz (The index * int(second input) + newline) * int(the second input)
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQp%2a%2B%2aNszbsz&input=%22Test%22%0A2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Test%22%0A2%0A%22UuU%22%0A3%0A%22A%22%0A5%0A%22ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%22%0A25&debug=0&input_size=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), <strike>82</strike> 75 bytes

```clj
#(dotimes[x(count %1)](dotimes[y %2](prn(apply str(repeat %2(get %1 x))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYxBCsIwEEX3OcUQKcwsG/EAHqIr6SKkU4mkSUgn0J4@Vhcign/5/uO5kB61cMOJZ1hsmGt04lNsJ5yS@IXX24Yu1SjQ9TR@4A6dGTGXiDbnsMMqBQtntodn8M4vHTZ6rxEo/GqDFl5FgyF1FHyUEOlHGOqg4fz/v2q4kGpP)

Uncompressed:

```clj
#(dotimes [x (count %1)]
  (dotimes [y %2]
    (prn
      (apply str
        (repeat %2 (get %1 x))))))
```

Edit: Shaved a few chars off the end by replacing a for loop with the stdlib repeat function.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 68 + 18 bytes

```cs
a=>n=>new int[a.Length*n].Select((x,i)=>Enumerable.Repeat(a[i/n],n))
```

Also included in byte count:

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDJUgIxED2br2g5SGKNcStPOFQhghuugKjIIcbWSdWQwSQjWBbfjpkZEdFXfej19euWdkMmBmepVfoV2h/W4ZC3lH6rEKLFEO1ISJzn60kco3Qq0ZYfoUajJPkk4CFjYS3Ucr/IZLBOOCXhPVHPcC6UpuyntGjK0Ey13LfOeA1BESjtAjhp6HSIRjzFuP/bl5EwVQ94gXAmwqr2hmPwM33BW6hfXbSuB7yNmVpKJ4FiYXUxz29whMJR0VebehBoxmb@2t96CimecJS6ylJlHKkYgdK8BCHU/S@SnFI8@7chZQxWQ9BpHMPaWsGQJUqPusSWmJY/kOFdGLCjWGW8@SBvZxEtQznwVma8F6FBOoGwCpOctcR4J6kZIz4oq/wjfKE5XX9rwLxgx6@Esfid2x6wbLalrKOMNxPTEDIqqOc39YxymB81WWxhfs/Kyv@WP@unZNmbkumsg9bBDummXdglNdgjtYP6YaN5dHxyetY6v7i8ur5pd7q3vbv7B9jZ@wI)

Output is a collection of collections of characters (one collection for each line).

Explanation:

```cs
a => n =>                                // Take a string and a number
    new int[a.Length * n]                // Create new collection, 'n' times larger than 'a'
    .Select((x, i) =>                    // Replace every member with
        Enumerable.Repeat(a[i / n], n)   //     a collection of repeated character from 'a', based on index
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/) v1.8, <s>63</s> <s>62</s> 58 bytes

```
#(map(fn[l](dotimes[i %2](prn(apply str(repeat %2 l)))))%)
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/Kksz/0)

## Explanation

```
(map ... s)           For every letter of the string 's'
(dotimes[i %2] ...)   Do 'n' times
(prn(apply str(repeat %2 l))) Repeat the letter 'n' times, combine to string and print
```

Answer (score 0):

### GNU APL, 11 bytes

```
⍪/⎕{⍺⍺⍴⍵}¨⍞
```

Left argument: `⍺` number of repetitions. `⍵` the string.

This uses `⍴` to repeat each letter (`⍵` in the inner `{}` block) in `⍺x⍺` matrix.

Then we use `⍪/` to "laminate" them.

Comment: Which APL is this? If it works on GNU APL, you can make `⍺ ⍺` `⍺⍺`. Also, it might be possible to make it `⍪/⎕{⍺⍺⍴⍵}¨⍞` by receiving input from STDIN (on GNU APL). (Fair warning, I haven't used gnu apl in a while. so this might be wrong.)

Comment: Yeah, I just verified, `⍪/⎕{⍺⍺⍴⍵}¨⍞` does work on GNU APL.

Comment: `⍪/⎕{⍺⍺⍴⍵}¨⍞` also works for 11 bytes, receiving input through STDIN (a line of text, then the number)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 49 bytes

```bash
sed s/./$(printf \&%.s `seq $[$1*$1]`)/g|fold -$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RaFYX09fRaOgKDOvJE0hRk1Vr1ghoTi1UEElWsVQS8UwNkFTP70mLT8nRUFXxfD//5DU4pL/RgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 46 bytes

```python
x,y=input()
for p in x:print'\n'.join([p*y]*y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v0Kn0jYzr6C0REOTKy2/SKFAITNPocKqoCgzr0Q9Jk9dLys/M08jukCrMlarUvP/f6WQ1OISJR0jAA)

Comment: Doesn’t really work for the white square emoji, but that might just be because of decoding errors. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v0Kn0jYzr6C0REOTKy2/SKFAITNPocKqoCgzr0Q9Jk9dLys/M08jukCrMlarUvP/f6VHa@a839GvpGNsDgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
*mÅn+m*~
```

String input as a list of characters.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/18r93BrnnauVt3//0YK0UohSjpKqUBcDMQlSrFcxkCxUCC7FIhDgXxTIN9RKRYA)

**Explanation:**

```python
*        # Repeat each character in the second (implicit) input-list the first
         # (implicit) input-integer amount of times
 mÅn+    # Append a newline to each inner string:
 m       #  Map over each string,
  Å      #  using the following two characters as inner code-block:
   n     #   Push a newline character
    +    #   And append it to the string
     m*  # Repeat each inner string the first (implicit) input-integer amount of times
       ~ # Dump this list of lines with trailing newlines to the stack
         # (after which the entire stack is joined and output implicitly as result)
```