# "cat"-like program

Tags: code-golf

The mission is to implement a `cat`-like program (copy all STDIN to STDOUT).

Rules:

- You may only use standard libraries
- Indentation must be either two spaces or a single tab (in languages which require indentation)
- Scripts must use shebangs
- The result of `cat anything.txt | ./yourprogram | diff anything.txt -` should be nothing and should not be an infinite loop

`Go` example (84 bytes)

```
package main
import (
  "os"
  "io"
)
func main() {
  io.Copy(os.Stdout,os.Stdin)
}
```

`C++` example (78 bytes)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  cout << cin.rdbuf();
}
```

`Ruby` example (44 bytes)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
$stdout << $stdin.read
```

Shortest code (by bytes) wins.

Comment: Two space indentation isn't valid in Python.

Comment: This indentation thing is nonsense

Comment: @edc65 Especially because it often isn't needed.

Comment: @ProgramFOX Stoning the Rosetta.

Comment: @TheRare I'm not sure where you heard that, but *any* indentation is perfectly valid in Python. Different levels don't even need to have the same indentation. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation

Comment: @Plutor Guess I've ran to some weird bugs then.

Comment: Even if there were a valid winning criterion, this seems a rather boring challenge.

Comment: The indentation rule doesn't make sense, the shebang one makes even less, because shebangs can be platform-specific, especially in the case of Python.

Comment: *until end of June 2914*… Woaah…

Comment: Also, *person with most implementation*? What?

Comment: what exactly prevents me from using `cat` in Bash, or all the 0 character programs in other languages?

Comment: typo indeed XD 2014

Comment: @TheRare With regards to Python indentation, it must be consistent *within a block*. So, each level must be self consistent, but it doesn't have to care about the other levels. If you aren't consistent within a block, then it will complain.

Comment: Why are there so many downvotes?

Comment: @professorfish: Because of the rules, I assume. Rule 2 is nonsense, rule 1 only makes sense for certain languages and counting the bytes of the shebang is a very weird form of scoring. So far, pretty much all answers seem to have ignored rule 3.

Comment: @Dennis would it be legitimate to just edit it to make it clearer?

Comment: @professorfish: The rules aren't unclear, they're just very, very strange. I don't think we should actually *change* the rules of a contest.

Comment: to bee correct with the size in my opinion also the size of the used interpreter must be added otherwise it is useless to compare the code snippets. also it should be cleared what happens if the code must be compiled to us (e.g java, c) what counts the size of the source code or the size of the binary ?

Comment: what about this python solution? `for s in' /\___/\|(  o o  )|/   *   \|\__\_/__/meow|  /   \| / ___ \| \/___\/'.split('|'):print s `

Comment: @professorfish, why are there so many upvotes?

Comment: this isn't even cat-like as much as it is echo-like.

Comment: Using `cat` with only one argument to just print out the file is easily the most frequent use case, but people apparently forget that `cat` stands for "concatenate" - most solutions here don't do that.

Comment: @orion: that's because OP ignored it too: "copy all stdin to stdout". Handling arguments is harder.

Comment: Sheesh why all the downvotes?

Answer (score 44):

## GolfScript, 0 characters / bytes

This could technically be considered invalid since GolfScript will append a `\n`, but that can be fixed with `:n;` (3 bytes).

Comment: Haha, +1. Explanation for people who don't speak golfscript: stdin is read to the stack when the program starts and the stack is outputted when it ends.

Comment: Nice idea, but invalid. GolfScript will append a linefeed to the input.

Comment: @Dennis That could be fixed in 3 bytes: `:n;` (edited)

Comment: I would say then that the zero-char solution is, unfortunately, invalid, and therefore the score is a solid 3. +1 nonetheless!

Answer (score 24):

## sed - 0 bytes

No command needed to cat a file with `sed`: all lines of input are printed without modification, so

```
sed ''
```

will act like `cat` for standard input, and

```
sed '' /etc/fstab
```

will print content of file.

Comment: "sed n" works for me and is one byte shorter.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Yes, thank you. I didn't count the quotes as part of the `sed` script (I considered an empty script, something similar to `sed -f /dev/null input`). If we are to count chars on the line, your proposal saves a byte indeed.

Answer (score 19):

## ΒrainFuck (5 bytes)

```
,[.,]
```

**Explanation:**

```
,  Read first byte of input and place on stack
[  While top byte is not 0...
 . Print top byte from stack as ASCII and remove
 , Read next byte of input and place on stack
]  ...loop
```

Comment: one of those few tasks where BF is shorter than most other things...

Comment: This is less than 2 bytes (each command is 3 bits... totaling 15 bits).

Comment: It is not 3 bits when stored in ASCII format, and I wrote it as ASCII.

Comment: This will fail on files with a null in them though..

Comment: @Claudiu how else would you tell when the file ends? This is BF :P

Answer (score 16):

## Haskell - 17 bytes

```hs
main=interact id
```

`id` is the identity function and from the documentation :

> The `interact` function takes a function of type `String->String` as its argument. The entire input from the standard input device is passed to this function as its argument, and the resulting string is output on the standard output device.

Answer (score 10):

## x86_64 NASM Assembly for Linux - 125 / 100

```
r:mov ax,0
mov di,0
mov rsi,c
mov dx,1
syscall
cmp ax,0
je e
mov di,1
syscall
jg r
e:mov ax,60
syscall
SECTION .bss
c:resw 1
```

I couldn't get it to fit in 100 bytes, but it is assembly.  Eight bytes could be saved at the cost of changing the return status to 1 instead of 0:

```
r:mov ax,0
mov di,0
mov rsi,c
mov dx,1
syscall
cmp ax,0
mov di,1
jg s
mov ax,60
s:syscall
jg r
SECTION .bss
c:resw 1
```

Now, if you really want 100 bytes, here is one in exactly 100 bytes.  The problem is that it doesn't exit correctly, it just segfaults:

```
r:mov ax,0
mov di,0
mov rsi,c
mov dx,1
syscall
cmp ax,0
mov di,1
syscall
jg r
SECTION .bss
c:resw 1
```

The instructions say to only use standard libraries; is there extra credit for using no libraries at all?

Answer (score 6):

## C 43

```
main(c){while((c=getchar())>=0)putchar(c);}
```

Comment: You can use `~(c=getchar())` instead of `(c=getchar())>=0` to save 2 characters.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: EOF is typically -1, but this is not guaranteed by the standard. The standard only defines about EOF in section 7.19.1:

    EOF which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and a negative value, that is returned by several functions to indicate end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream;

Comment: `main(){for(;putchar(getchar())<127;);}` what's with that? (apparently putchar's return value is casted to int so EOF becomes 255)

Comment: @bebe yes it's pity. putchar get an int but truncates it to 8 bits. (It's in the spec)

Comment: @edc65 VC++ error C2065: 'c':undeclared identifier. Yes, sorry my comment about putchar was incorrect.

Comment: @bacchusbeale compile as C, not C++. 'c' is defined as the first argument of main function

Answer (score 5):

### Linux/Unix tools, 16 bytes

```
#!/bin/sh
grep $
```

Other tools that work when called by bash/sh are

```
tr . .
```

and (15 bytes)

```
sed n
```

EDIT: Changed title from "bash/sh" to "Linux/Unix tools" because although the tools can be called by bash or sh they aren't actually part of bash or sh.

Comment: Copies the indentation?

Comment: @TheRare yes.  It copies "all stdin to the stdout," as required.  I guess that the 2-space indentation requirement refers to indentation of the code.

Comment: Yes, yes it does.

Comment: shebangs don't count towards your score (and why are they `#!/bin/sh`? that isn't bash)

Comment: @professorish /bin/sh is Bash on my platform (Ubuntu 14.04)  Perhaps I should have said Ubuntu and RedHat Fedora in my answer instead of "many systems" (will edit accordingly).  In the example for ruby shown in the question, the shebang is counted among the 44 bytes.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson hmmm I have Ubuntu 14.04 and `/bin/sh` definitely goes to the Bourne shell... nevermind

Comment: No modern system uses a plain Bourne shell as `/bin/sh`. Today `/bin/sh` is usually the Almquist shell, bash, or ksh93. OpenBSD uses pdksh as `/bin/sh`. A modern `/bin/sh` has POSIX features like `export PARAM=value` and `echo $((1 + 2))`. The classic SVR4 Bourne shell has fewer features but should still be enough to run this answer.

Comment: `tr` is part of the toolbox, `tr` is not `bash`

Comment: @Emmanuel neither is `grep`; in fact `tr` is more in Bash than `grep`, because `tr` is in coreutils and `grep` isn't

Answer (score 5):

## Node.js 55

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: Could shorten by assigning `p=process` first to avoid repetition. Just plain `#!env node` works unless you've got a non-standard filesystem layout or funky `$PATH` stuff going on. Alternatively, drop the shebang line (so the default `sh` is used) and do `node -e '<program>'` because that's the same (6) extra number of characters and stays system-general. (If you want to join the dark side, rename your `node` binary to `n`.) Aaand drop the semicolon.

Answer (score 5):

## Bash, 3

If you need a shebang, `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` is probably fine.

Had to be done. Hopelessly uncreative.

```
cat
```

Slightly more interesting:

```
tee
```

Normally, `tee FILENAME` sends its input both to the file and to standard output. Without an argument, it seems to behave like `cat`.

## Bash, 2

...if you don't mind the status message at the end and the fact that the output only comes after EOF on standard input!

```
dd
```

Removing the status message costs 4 chars for a total of 6 chars:

```
dd 2>a
```

The message is sent to the file `a` instead of standard output.

If you dispose of the message entirely, the total length is <del>14</del> 7:

```
dd 2>&-
```

## Bash/[SHELF](https://github.com/professorfish/bash-shelf), 1

For the shebang, try

```
#!/bin/sh
. shelf.sh
```

where `shelf.sh` is the location of your SHELF file.

SHELF is my PYG-like golfing library for Bash.

```
D
```

`D` just aliases to `cat`. Also uncreative.

And the alias for `tee` is...

```
5
```

Comment: `2>&-` is shorter than `2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 5):

### Perl (1)

0+1 for the -p parameter

If really the shebang counts, invoke it like this: `perl -p nul` on M$ or `perl -p /dev/null` on *nix so no shebang is involved :P

```
D:\>copy con cat.pl
#!perl -p
^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

D:\>type cat.pl
#!perl -p

D:\>type cat.pl | cat.pl
#!perl -p

D:\>
```

Answer (score 4):

## CJam - 1

```
q
```

No extra newline :)

Answer (score 3):

## AWK - ???

The complete program in `awk` has only 1 char:

```
1
```

Unluckily the shebang stuff lets kinda explode it's length :(

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
1
```

May I copy `awk` into the filesystem root?  >;-)

As oneliner it is shorter:

```
$ awk 1 </etc/hostname 
darkstar
```

I'm not sure what counts and what not...

Comment: In my experience, code in codegolf doesn't use shebangs, it is intended to be directly executed by the  interpreter (awk in this case).

Comment: Thinking about `stdout = g(f(stdin))`... `<input tac|tac >output` fails if the last input line has no linefeed. I like `<input rev|rev >output`. So far for `f = g`. What comes into the game for `f != g`? `tr` and it's inverse? `sed` and backwards? Smells not really promising...

Comment: A flash of enlightenment hit me: `tee` ftw!!! :)

Comment: At least in OpenBSD, `printf 'full\0string' | awk 1` outputs 'full\n', so it is not perfect. I wonder if gawk or mawk does better?

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 2 bytes (or 1?)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -p
```

The question states that the shabang needs to be included. The 2 bytes counted is the `-p` part of the shebang. The otherwise empty script makes Ruby behave *exactly* likes `cat` when run with the `p` switch: Run it without arguments and it will take input from stdin, or with arguments and it print the contents of those files.

**edit:**

## Ruby, 8 bytes

@core1024 had already posted a solution in Perl similar to the one above, so here is another attempt. Note that the following are not scripts, they are Ruby *programs* ;)

```
puts *$<
```

## Ruby, 16 bytes

I think this one is cute

```
print while gets
```

Answer (score 3):

## 16 bit .com binary for MSDOS - 31 Bytes (112 Byte NASM Source)

```
00 00 BA 00 00 B9 01 00 B4 3F BB 00 00 CD 21 83 F8 00 74 09 B4 40 BB 01 00 CD 21 EB EB CD 20
```

The nasm source code:

```
c:resw 1
mov dx,c
mov cx,1
r:
mov ah,63
mov bx,0
int 33
cmp ax,0
je e
mov ah,64
mov bx,1
int 33
jmp r
e:
int 32
```

Build with "nasm -f bin -o cat.com cat-msdos.s".

I already provided a solution for x86_64 Linux, but was unable to get it under 100 bytes. This is over 100 bytes of assembly, but the actually binary is only 31 bytes!  This must be the simplest solution here.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.x - 56 or 61 bytes

Input limited to 10^9 bytes.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
from os import*
write(1,read(0,10**9))
```

Or for infinite input (61 bytes):

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
from sys import*
stdout.write(stdin.read())
```

Not much to say, is there?

Comment: This isn't `cat` because it adds a linefeed or whatever your system uses (cr+lf?) to the output.

Comment: @yeti You're right. I use Windows atm, so couldn't remember that. Fixing...

Comment: @yeti Better now?

Comment: You can use `1e9` instead of `10**9` to save 2 characters. Also, the shebang doesn't count towards character count.

Comment: @nyuszika7h `1e9` is float while `os.read` requires an int. Also, the question specifically says to include the shebang.

Comment: I see. You can use `import sys;print sys.stdin.read(),` (note the trailing comma) for the second example to save 11 characters.

Comment: @nyuszika7h That prints an extra space.

Comment: I should check my suggestions before posting them. >_> It actually prints a **newline** for me. Python is weird.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman I know. This answer uses Python 2.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman I don't see a reason to use Python 3 yet. Python 2 is faster and often better for golfing.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Ah, sorry then.

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp

### ECL, 106

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ecl -shell
(ignore-errors(loop(write-byte(read-byte *standard-input*)*standard-output*)))
```

### SBCL, 109

```
#!/usr/local/bin/sbcl --script
(ignore-errors(loop(write-byte(read-byte *standard-input*)*standard-output*)))
```

### CLISP, <s>188</s> 180

```
#!/usr/local/bin/clisp
(let((i(make-stream 0 :element-type'(mod 256)))(o(make-stream 1
:direction :output :element-type'(mod
256))))(ignore-errors(loop(write-byte(read-byte i)o))))
```

These are the shortest programs that I can make, yet none are under 100 bytes.

The main problem is that `*standard-input*` and `*standard-output*` are character streams, not byte streams. A simple `(loop(write-char(read-char))` would copy the characters but would fail to preserve bytes that did not form valid characters. Now my Common Lisp implementations want to use UTF-8 (perhaps because my locale is UTF-8), but I want to copy binary files that my not be valid UTF-8. Therefore I must copy bytes, not characters.

In ECL and SBCL, standard input and output are bivalent for both bytes and characters. I may use `read-byte` and `write-byte`, but those functions lack default streams, so I must pass `*standard-input*` and `*standard-output*` as arguments.

CLISP insists that `*standard-input*` and `*standard-output*` transport only characters. The way around this is to call `ext:make-stream` on file descriptor 0 (standard input) and file descriptor 1 (standard output) to make binary streams.

All three programs loop byte by byte. This is a **slow** way to copy bytes. A faster way would use a vector of 16384 bytes with `read-sequence` and `write-sequence`, but the program would be longer.

Answer (score 2):

## Batch (8)

```
type CON
```

Type writes file content to the console and CON is treated as a file containing all console input.

Comment: I like how this has a one-to-one correspondence with Bash: `type` to `cat`, `con` to `/dev/stdin`

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 12

```
While 1:Input Str1:Disp Str1:End
```

Comment: Use "Str1" instead of "A".

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Thanks for the tip, I was really bad at TI-Basic a year ago. Only problem is you can't use the `STO->` arrow but you couldn't before either. It seems so silly that I used A instead of a string var :P again, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ThomasKwa Good idea.

Answer (score 2):

## Java <s>68</s> 104

My first approach at this:

<s>`class a{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(a[0]);}}`</s>

EDIT: Yeah, I misunderstood the concept, here is another attempt, I couldn't get it done in less than 100 chars so I'd appreciate any suggestion:

```
class a{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{for(;;)System.out.write(System.in.read());}}
```

Comment: That's not how `cat` works. `cat` displays the *contents* of the file(s) given as command line arguments, or takes input from stdin when there are no arguments.

Comment: @daniero Yeah I wasn't right, it works now, although much longer.

Comment: This breaks the rule about looping forever, how about: class a{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{int r;while(0<(r=System.in.read()))System.out.write(r);}}

Answer (score 2):

## zsh, 15 bytes

```
#!/bin/zsh
1<&1
```

Note that there is **no** newline at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Some Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print<>;
```

25 bytes with shebang. This can also be much smaller with die(), and by bending the rules ever so slightly:

```
die<>
```

Executing the 4th test could only be done like this:

```
cat bla|perl ./perlcat 2>&1|diff bla -
```

<> is an abbreviation for `<STDIN>`. The 25 byte print example is pretty self explanatory. die() is normally used for exiting non-zero and outputting an error message, hence using the 2>&1 to bend the rules around the 4th test.

It also appears that the semicolon is not required for the last statement in Perl, so the first example could be brought down to 24 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

#### Perl6, 14 bytes:

```
.say for lines
```

And, if it doesn't need to be deterministically printing it in the correct order (hehe), you can use the auto-threading "map-apply"

```
lines>>.say
```

Answer (score 2):

## ><>, 7 bytes

I know a ><> solution already exists, but I figured it would be welcome.

```
i:0(?;o
```

[Click here to try it](http://fishlanguage.com/playground/u7ttRxRqTCymDDNe6)

Answer (score 1):

## GML, 37

```
while(1)show_message(keyboard_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rust - 74

Really generic...

```
use std::io;fn main(){for l in io::stdin().lines(){io::print(l.unwrap())}}
```

### No Comment - 12

```
'=|@^:'&|:'&
```

Unimplemented, so, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

### Dart - 48

```
import"dart:io";main(){stdout.addStream(stdin);}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy - 45 bytes

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
System.out << System.in
```

And test:

```
$ cat FirstJsonObj.groovy | ./Cats.groovy | diff FirstJsonObj.groovy  -
$
```

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl 57

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
while {[gets stdin d]>=0} {puts $d}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 32

```
while let l=readLine(){print(l)}
```

Prints every line until EOF is reached

If you're really picky that this doesn't work with an empty line at the end or whatever you can use this:

```
while let l=readLine(stripNewline:false){print(l,terminator:"")}
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 18 bytes

```
fprintf(input(''))
```

Cannot use `disp` as it appends a newline to the output.

Answer (score 1):

## [Simplex v.0.7](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Simplex/)

```
bg
b  ~~ take string input
 g ~~ output strip
```

Simple enough.

Comment: I need an "output all" character now. c:

Answer (score 1):

## [TeaScript](https://esolangs.org/wiki/TeaScript), 1 byte

```
x
```

Input is given in the first input field.
Compile online [here](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/?code=x&input=Write_your_input_here).

Answer (score 0):

## Shell script, 11 bytes (including shebang)

```
#!/bin/cat
```

Comment: XD somehow my `cat` was on `/usr/bin/cat` XD

Comment: This isn't technically a shell script, it's a `cat` script. The shell isn't involved for executables with a shebang, unless the shebang happens to point to the shell.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Arguably it's a shell script that's just using `cat` *as* the shell.

Comment: But this is not a cat program. This is a quine.

Comment: @user23013 Oh, so it is.

Answer (score 0):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 52 Bytes

```
use IO;func main(){println(File.readText(args[0]));}
```

Expanded:

```
use IO;

func main () {
    println(File.readText(args[0]));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## grep - 2 or 7 bytes

```
grep ''
```

Tested on Linux.

The "program" of '' is two bytes but the complete command is 7 bytes.

Comment: Actually, `''` as a grep program won't work (try `printf "#!/bin/grep\n''" > prog; chmod +x prog; ./prog`). In your example, `''` is just shell quote syntax. I can't see a way to run this with `grep` as interpreter, so this should count as a 7-byte shell script.

Comment: '' as a program will work from the interactive shell:

"seq 100 | grep '' | md5sum" produces the same result as
"seq 100 | md5sum"  (ignore the double quotes)

Answer (score -2):

### Many languages (49)

```
print("\\    /\\\n )  ( \')\n(  /  )\n \\(__)|");
```

> Because :3 is more like a tame lion.

Comment: That's not what the question is asking for, although it sounds like it :)

Comment: I couldn't resist!

Answer (score -2):

## Ruby, 21 characters

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
while 1;puts gets;end
```

Comment: but it won't stop '___'

Comment: testing command: `cat anything.txt | ./cat.rb`

Comment: neither will cat

Comment: @fogcityben For me `cat` stops looping when it reads EOF. What version of `cat` are you working from?