# Find i^n, given n

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, complex-numbers

**The Challenge**

In as few characters as possible, find the value of \$i^n\$, given \$n\$, a positive integer greater than 0. This should be outputted as a String.

For those that don't know, \$i\$ is defined such that \$i^2=-1\$. So:

- \$i^1=i\$
- \$i^2=-1\$
- \$i^3=-i\$
- \$i^4=1\$

This then repeats..

**Rules**

- If your language supports complex numbers, don't use any functions or arithmetic that could work this out.
- Floating point inaccuracies are fine for answers that would return decimals anyway, but integer inputs should give exact results

**Bonus Points**

-5 if you can work the value out where n is also negative

-15 if you can work out the value for any real number (this bonus includes the -5 from the above bonus)

Good luck!

Comment: In what format do we return exactly? Through function output or stdout?

Comment: @proudhaskeller The tag wiki lists defaults for that. Unless specified otherwise, functions and programs are fine, input via function argument, STDIN or command-line argument and output via STDOUT or function return value. Functions do not have to be named.

Comment: @MartinBüttner but if i choose function output, how should the output should be formatted/stored without native complex numbers in my language?

Comment: If you support any real number you can output in any valid complex form. So just 1 would be valid and so would 1+0i.

Comment: Well I think that floating point inaccuracies are fine for answers that would return decimals anyway, but integer inputs should give exact results. (This is my first question posed so if you disagree let me know!)

Comment: Okay, I shall do!

Comment: Do we require the use of floating point integers?

Comment: @BetaDecay What are floating point integers? o.O

Comment: @MartinBüttner Haha wrong word :/ Floating point number then

Comment: Common Lisp, (26 characters - 15 = **11**): `(lambda(n)(expt #C(0 1)n))`. Unfortunately, this is against the rules :-(

Comment: I feel so stupid. I only just realized that python has a built in `complex` type.

Comment: i is not defined as the square root of -1. Rather, it is defined such that i^2 = -1, which is not the same, since one can choose plus or minus the root of -1.

Comment: @user1997744 True, I'll edit it now although I doubt it'll make any difference..

Comment: mod 4 and a lookup. This doesn't seem very interesting.

Comment: @user1997744 in all fairness, it is possible to define square root that way as well, making it unique by taking a branch cut.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Ruby, score -2

(13 bytes, -15 bonus)

```
->n{[1,90*n]}
```

Features include: no rounding errors! (if you pass the input as a Rational)

---

**posted by the author, Kezz101**

> If you support any real number you can output in any valid complex form.

Negatives scores make my adrenaline rush forth. Thus the rules <strike>get abused</strike> are made use of to achieve this noble goal.

Creates an anonymous function and outputs an array with 2 entries representing a complex number in polar form (angular unit: degrees).

Comment: "Ruby, -2 bytes".....

Comment: So, does downloading this 1,000,000,000,000 times give me 2TB of free hard drive space? Sounds like a good deal to me.

Comment: ^ My browser broke down before I succeeded to do that. Maybe try a "zip bomb" with the file inside? (Extracting it saves space.)

Answer (score 14):

## CJam, 12 characters - 5 = 7

```
1'iW"-i"]li=
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Supports negative inputs.

```
1              "Push 1.";
 'i            "Push the character i.";
   W           "Push -1.";
    "-i"       "Push the string -i.";
        ]      "Wrap all four in an array.";
         li    "Read STDIN and convert to integer.";
           =   "Access array. The index is automatically taken module the array length.";
```

The result is printed automatically at the end of the program.

## Mathematica, <s>22</s> <s>20</s> 19 characters - 15 = 4

```
Sin[t=π#/2]i+Cos@t&
```

This is an anonymous function, which you can use like

```
Sin[t=π#/2]i+Cos@t&[15]
```

(Or assign it to `f` say, and then do `f[15]`.)

Supports reals and gives exact results for integer input.

Note that the `i` is *not* Mathematica's complex *i* (which is `I`). It's just an undefined variable.

Also, despite the order of the expression, Mathematica will reorder the output into `R+Ci` form.

Comment: You don't need the `4%`. It can be done automatically.

Comment: @user23013 nifty :)

Comment: Shouldn't the two answers be separate?

Comment: @Quincunx Maybe... originally they were both in CJam, which is why I put them in the same answer. But the second one wasn't valid, so I ported it to Mathematica, but left it where it was. If people insist I can split them up.

Comment: And you can save a character in using it with `f@15` instead of `f[15]`.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I'm not counting that. The byte count is only for the function definition, not for using it.

Comment: @MartinBüttner: Yep, I know. Just pointing out that using it is brief too.

Comment: You can also change Pi to π to save a char

Comment: @miles Oh right, I somehow thought scoring is in bytes, but the question mentions characters, yay! :)

Answer (score 14):

### Python 2 - (24-5)=19

```
lambda n:'1i--'[n%4::-2]
```

Most credit belongs to @user2357112, I just golfed his answer from the comments on [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41726/31625) a bit more.

Explanation: Starts at the index `n%4` in the string `'1i--'`. Then iterates backwards in steps of two over each letter in the string. So, for example, `n=6` would start at index 2, the first `-`, then skip the `i` and take the `1`, to return `-1`.

@xnor pointed out a same-length solution:

```
lambda n:'--i1'[~n%4::2]
```

### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/) - (14-5)=9

I can only seem to get 14, no matter how I try to reverse/slice/etc. :'(

```
%_2<"1i--"h%Q4
```

Which is essentially the same as the above python answer, but in 2 steps, because pyth doesn't support the full indexing options of python. [Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

I'm going to go have a talk with isaacg about Pyth indexing ;)

Comment: Doesn't the python `lambda` need to be assigned to a variable? At the vary least, to call it you'd need to surround it with parentheses, adding two bytes so it could be called `(lambda...)(n)`.

Comment: @mbomb007 [According to meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1503/31625) this is acceptable. The code here creates a function that performs the task a required. Anonymous lambdas are used relatively frequently in python for functions like `map` and `sorted`.

Answer (score 11):

### TI-BASIC (NSpire) - 5 (20 characters-15)

```
cos(nπ/2)+sin(nπ/2)i
```

If you want to recieve a complex return value, replace the `i` at the end with ``(complex i).

Comment: @MartinBüttner TI-Basic seems to use some kind of 'Expression' type, and the built-in methods return exact results for these.

Comment: I see, all good then. ;)

Comment: What about the rule "If your language supports complex numbers, don't use any functions or arithmetic that could work this out." +i is arithmetic

Comment: @edc65 The + is actually a complex operation. However, if you don't like that, replace the `` with a normal `i`. If the variable `i` is not defined, you'll get the complex number, just with `i` instead of ``. I'm just calculating the real and imaginary parts separately.

Comment: @Shujal In that case, I think you should use `i` anyway. The complex i isn't even the character the question asks for, and it'll save you two bytes, so you'd at least tie with me ;).

Comment: Scoring is in characters, so that's 20 characters/score 5 for you.

Answer (score 7):

## [Marbelous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40808/8478), 43 bytes

Not really a winner, but Marbelous is fun. :)

```
}0
^0
=0&2
&1
}0
^1\/
=0&02D3169
\/\/&0&1&2
```

This is a program which reads the input as a single integer from the first command-line argument. Note that the input is taken modulo 256, but this doesn't affect validity of the result for inputs greater than 255, because 256 is divisible by 4.

### Explanation

Marbelous is a 2D programming language, which simulates "marbles" (byte values) falling through a bunch of devices. The board is made up of 2-character wide cells (the devices), which can process the marbles. Everything that falls off the bottom of a board is printed to STDOUT.

Let's go through the devices in use:

- `}0` is where the first command-line argument goes. I've used two instances of this device, so I get two copies of the input value (at the same time).
- `^n` checks for the `n`th bit of the input marble (where `n=0` is the least significant bit), and produces `1` or `0` depending on the bit.
- `=0` checks for equality with `0`. If the input marble is equal, it just drops straight through, if it isn't it is pushed to the right.
- `\/` is a trash can, so it just swallows the input marble and never produces anything.
- `2D` is the ASCII code of `-`, `31` is the ASCII code of `1` and `69` is the ASCII code of `i`.
- The `&n` are synchronisers. Synchronisers stall a marble until all synchronisers with the same `n` hold a marble, at which point they'll all let their stored marble fall through.

So in effect, what I do is to hold the three relevant characters in three synchronisers, and release those depending on how the least significant bits are set in the input.

For more information, [see the spec draft](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/docs/blob/master/spec-draft.md).

Comment: I really like this one! Marbelous sounds fab I'll need to check it out sometime soon :)

Comment: @Kezz101 We've got a spec draft [over here](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/docs/blob/master/spec-draft.md)

Comment: Oh nice! It looks really interesting

Comment: Don't forget that you can give inputs to the main board on the command line, so this board could be used as-is.

Comment: @Sparr Yes, but supplying small bytes via command line argument is annoying.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I'm pretty sure that command line "1" is marble 0x01

Comment: @Sparr Oh okay, I thought command-line arguments were read like STDIN, byte-for-byte.

Comment: @MartinBüttner You can ditch the last row, saving 3 bytes, you'll be printing zero width characters, but I doubt that that's a problem.

Comment: @overactor Hm, I don't know... outputting additional characters (even if they're unprintable) still seems to violate the output format for me. Might be worth a meta question though.

Comment: I feel like you could stack things differently and save a line here. Will the two processing chains (below the two duped inputs) fit side by side in any way?

Comment: @Sparr maybe with cylindrical boards?

Comment: I think you need another \/ under the first &0 to avoid dropping a 0x01 to stdout before a "-"

Comment: here's my test harness, if it's useful: `for i in 1 2 3 4; do marbelous.py powersofi.mbl $i | hexdump -C ; done`

Comment: @Sparr ah, you're right. I think I've fixed it without using extra characters.

Comment: @MartinBüttner now the matble in the upper `&2` synchronizer is falling through and triggering the `&0`, causing you to print -i in stead of i for input%4 == 1.

Comment: @overactor oh right, I should probably terminate the board instead. Will test later.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6) 29-5 = 24

Supports negative power.

```js
f=n=>(n&2?'-':'')+(n&1?'i':1)
```

ES5 :

```js
function f(n){return (n&2?'-':'')+(n&1?'i':1)}
```

Comment: Yep, shorter (`f=n=>[1,'i',-1,'-i'][n%4]`). But it's less sexy and it won't support negative powers. It depends on the bonus I guess.

Comment: Nop, 29 bytes. Negative are supported with this code.

Comment: Does JS have a bitwise `&` operator? If so you can do `&3`for a true modulus-4 operation. Edit: looks like it does as `&2` is used in your answer...

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 chars - 15 bonus = score -7

The built-in (and thus prohibited) function is `0J1*⊢`, but this uses [@blutorange's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47446/43319).

```apl
¯12○.5×○
```

The challenge author, Kezz101, [wrote](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41719/find-in-given-n#comment97114_41719):

> If you support any real number you can output in any valid complex form.

This returns a complex number in the form `aJb` which is the normal way for APL to display complex numbers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///PzMgvzy16FHbhEPrDY0eTe/WMz08HUj9dyutqoKIplpmgUltEAtEP@papPCod65CempJsUJRZopCfppCWk5@YklmXrpCQX5mXolCalFRflEx2BAFiA0KhgpGCsYKJgqmXMiiQJOB2AiIjYHYBIhR5Q30DIHYCIiNgdgEiE0B)

#### Explanation

`¯12○` find the unit vector which has the angle in radians of

`.5×` one half times

`○` the argument multiplied by  (the circle constant)

Answer (score 5):

## Python 28 bytes - 5 = 23

Supports -ve inputs.

Assuming lambda functions are acceptable (Thanks FryAmTheEggman!):

```
lambda n:n%4/2*'-'+'1i'[n%2]
```

#### otherwise 31 bytes - 5 = 26

```
print[1,"i",-1,"-i"][input()%4]
```

Comment: :) Also, if you are allowed to use anonymous lambdas (I _think_ the meta consensus was yes...) `lambda n:[1,"i",-1,"-i"][n%4]` is shorter

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I'm a python noob.  How do I call such a thing?

Comment: You can't call it exactly. You have to store it somewhere you can access. So you could do `foo=...`, or you could do `map(<your lambda>,range(10))` to get a list of values of `i^n` from `0-9`.

Comment: Basically you are making a function pointer, if that is more clear :P

Comment: You're supposed to output a string.

Comment: @user2357112 I assume the print version is fine.  Are you saying I should quote the 1 and -1 in the lambda version?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: Yes, although you may be able to do better with string slicing tricks. For example, `lambda n:'--1i'[n%4-2::2]`.

Comment: @user2357112 - thats cool, though I feel guilty taking that as my best answer as I still don't fully understand what you did, and certainly wouldn't have come up with it myself.  If you make your own answer with this I'll upvote for sure.  Meanwhile I added my best effort which returns strings (and a leading space unfortunately)

Comment: To translate user2357112's post: Take every other character from `'--1i'` starting at index `n%4-2`. When python gets a negative index, it will start that many positions left from the end of the array, and then go up to `0`. This way, `0` and `1` don't ever hit the `-` signs, while `3` and `4` do.

Comment: `lambda n:n%4/2*'-'+'1i'[n%2]` Removes the space and is shorter :)

Comment: @user2357112 Very clever! Another char off: `'--i1'[~n%4::2]`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 14 bytes - 5 = 9

As a ring, \$\mathbb{C}\$ is isomorphic to \$\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)\$.

```
n->i^n%(i^2+1)
```

The `i` here is just a symbol, not the imaginary unit (which is `I` in Pari/GP).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y4zLk9VIzPOSNtQ839afpFGHlBc19BARwGEFQqKMvNKgGJKCrp2QCJNI09TU/M/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## (Emacs) Lisp – 34

Just for fun, in (Emacs) Lisp:

```lisp
(lambda(n)(elt[1 i -1 -i](% n 4)))
```

If you want to use it, use a `defun` or use `funcall`:

```
(funcall
 (lambda (n) (elt [1 i -1 -i] (% n 4)))
 4) => 1

(mapcar
 (lambda(n)(elt[1 i -1 -i](% n 4)))
 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8])
 => (1 i -1 -i 1 i -1 -i 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 29 - 5 = 24 bytes

```r
c(1,"i",-1,"-i")[scan()%%4+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P1nDUEcpU0lHF0jpZippRhcnJ@ZpaKqqmmgbxv435DLiMuYy4TLlMuMy57Lg@g8A)

Same as most methods above, takes a modulo of 4, and increases that by 1, because R's arrays are 1-indexed. Works for negative integers as well.

I was worried about mixed outputs here, but Giuseppe pointed out that R coerces numeric types to string types when they are mixed.

Comment: [29 - 5 = 24 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P1nDUEcpU0lHF0jpZippRhcnJ@ZpaKqqmmgbxv435DLiMuYy4TLlMuMy57Lg@g8A)

Comment: @Giuseppe Totally blanked on that. My concern with that is that the output is technically mixed, half string, half numeric.

Comment: nope, R automatically coerces `numeric` types to `character` when they're mixed! [Hadley's book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) explains this pretty well -- just Ctrl + F to "Coercion" and you'll see it, but the whole book is worth a read (for non-golfing purposes mostly, but sometimes you pick up a trick or two, heheh)

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 28 bytes -5 = 23

```powershell
('i',-1,'-i',1)["$args"%4-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V9DPVNdR9dQR10XSBtqRiupJBalFyupmugaxv6v5eLSNTTQ0zM0qFGtVlKJV7BSUNFQU0lTUInXVKr9DwA)

Port of all the cyclic indexing

Answer (score 3):

## Pure bash, 29 bytes - 5 = 24

Supports -ve inputs.

```
a=(1 i -1 -i)
echo ${a[$1%4]}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge-98, <s>41-5 = 36</s> <s>35-5 = 30</s> 32-5 = 27

```
&4%:01-`!4*+:2%'8*'1+\2/d*' +,,@
```

Supports negative integers. Not going to win any awards with this solution, but whatever.

It just accepts a number as input, does some trickery on the modulus (which, frustratingly, doesn't work like usual modulus for negative numbers in the interpreter I used to test it) to make negatives work, and then does some silly conditionals to decide what each character should be.

I'm sure this can be golfed down plenty further. For now, here's another solution that doesn't accept negatives, but makes up for the loss of the bonus by being shorter:

## Befunge-98, <s>32</s> <s>26</s> 23

```
&4%:2%'8*'1+\2/d*' +,,@
```

*Edit* - Now takes advantage of the fact that "-" is 13 (0xd) characters away from " ".

*Edit 2* - Now, again, takes advantage of the fact that "i" is 56 (0x38, or `'8`) characters away from "1".

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB, 33 bytes - 5 = 28

```
x={'i','-1','-i','1'};x(mod(n,4))
```

Even though it's a few bytes more (37-5=32), I actually like this approach better:

```
x='1i -';x((mod([n/2,n],2)>=1)+[3,1])
```

Comment: `i^3` is `-i`, rather than `i`, guess it just adds 1 char. -- Sidenote for other readers: without the first rule of the challenge, the Matlab solution would only be 3 characters long.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Fixed! Thanks for noticing... At least the second (a bit more interesting) approach is correct =)

Answer (score 3):

## **Java 8 Score: 72**

In Java, the worst golfing language ever!
Golfed:

```
java.util.function.Function s=n->{new String[]{"i","-1","-i","1"}[n%4]};
```

Expanded:

```
class Complex{

    java.util.function.Function s = n -> {new String[]{"i","-1","-i","1"}[n%4]};

}
```

Note: I'm not used to Java 8. I also do not have the runtime for it yet. Please tell me if there are any syntax errors. This is also my first golf.

**Edit:** Removed `import`.

**Edit:** Removed class declaration.

Another answer with score = 87 - 15 = 72

```
java.util.function.Function s=n->{Math.cos(n*Math.PI/2)+"+"+Math.sin(n*Math.PI/2)+"i"};
```

Expanded:

```
class Complex{

    java.util.function.Function s = n -> {Math.cos(n * Math.PI/2) + " + " + Math.sin(n * Math.PI/2) + "i"};

}
```

Comment: You can save some with "import java.util.*"

Comment: @Anubian Noob Class Function is in package `java.util.function` not `java.util` (or am I wrong?).

Comment: But if you do `java.util.*` the `.*` means import everything under the package. Just like you're currently importing all classes in the `fuction` package.

Comment: @ Anubian Noob `import` only imports the classes in that package. It does not import any of the classes from packages in that package. For example, class `Function` is in package `java.util.function` but not in package `java.util`.

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry about that.

Comment: I soooo have to update my Java skills :/

Comment: I don't think the challenge requires a class declaration.

Answer (score 3):

## C 77

```
main(){int n;scanf("%d",&n);char c[]={n%4>1?'-':' ',~n%2?'1':'i',0};puts(c);}
```

Improved thanks to Ruslan

## C 74-5=69

Oh and of course the most obvious approach

```
main(){unsigned n,*c[]={"1","i","-1","-i"};scanf("%d",&n);puts(c[n%4]);}
```

Comment: You can remove parentheses around `n%2` and use `~` instead of `!` because negating `n` first, then `%`ing with 2 will give the same result, at least for `n<(1<<32)-1`. And C doesn't require to explicitly define return type for function, so you can remove `int ` at the beginning. And also use `0` instead of `'\0'`. Thus -9 chars.

Answer (score 3):

## Java: <s>151</s> 131-5=126

Golfed:

```
class A{public static void main(String[]a){int n=Integer.parseInt(a[0]);System.out.print(n%4==0?"1":n%4==1?"i":n%4==2?"-1":"-i");}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
        System.out.print(n % 4 == 0 ? "1" : n % 4 == 1 ? "i" : n % 4 == 2 ? "-1" : "-i");
    }
}
```

#### As a function: 72-5=67

Golfed:

```
void f(int n){System.out.print(n%4==0?"1":n%4==1?"i":n%4==2?"-1":"-i");}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public void f(int n) {
    System.out.print(n % 4 == 0 ? "1" : n % 4 == 1 ? "i" : n % 4 == 2 ? "-1" : "-i");
}
```

Yes, yet another Java reply - and golfed even worse than ever. But you work with what you can...

***EDIT***: added function version.

***EDIT 2***: so, after a bit of trial and error, here's a version that tries to do it by the book, without exploring the cycle loophole. So…

#### Java with value calculation: 146-15=131

Golfed:

```
class B{public static void main(String[]a){float n=Float.parseFloat(a[0]);System.out.print(Math.cos((n*Math.PI)/2)+Math.sin((n*Math.PI)/2)+"i");}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
class B {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        float n = Float.parseFloat(a[0]);
        System.out.print(Math.cos((n * Math.PI) / 2) + Math.sin((n * Math.PI) / 2) + "i");
    }
}
```

(at least, I think I can claim the top bonus, correct me otherwise)

Comment: you could reduced your code, if you pass it to main as argument.

Comment: @user902383 I could always make a function, indeed. Probably will post both versions, too.

Comment: actually i was thinking about parsing it, so you will have `int n = Integer.parseInt(a[0])`

Comment: @user902383 Daaaaamn, didn't even remember that. *thumbs up*

Answer (score 3):

## OCaml 47

```
let m n=List.nth["1";"i";"-1";"-i"](n mod 4);;
```

Not an award winning solution, but this is my first time code-golfing, so I'm not exactly sure of what I'm doing.
I tried to use pattern matching, but that got me over 58.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score 5 (10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) - 5 bonus)

```
1'i®„-i)Iè
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fUD3z0LpHDfN0MzU9D6/4/1/XEAA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R@iEXJ0R1mlvZLCo7ZJCkr2/w3VMw@te9QwTzdTs/Lwiv86/wE).

**Explanation:**

```python
1           # Push 1
 'i        '# Push character "i"
   ®        # Push -1
    „-i     # Push string "-i"
       )    # Wrap everything on the stack into a list: [1,"i",-1,"-i"]
        Iè  # Use the input to (modular 0-based) index into it
            # (and output the result implicitly)
```

Comment: I think you've got it the wrong way round: \$i^0 = 1\$, not \$i\$. Fix it like [this](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R@iEXJ0R1mlvZKCrp2Ckv1/Q/XMQ@seNczTzdSsPLziv85/AA).

Comment: @TheThonnu Wait, you're completely right.. I must have accidently swapped your and my own test suite when I checked with the four provided test cases in the challenge description earlier today.. So sorry, my bad. Weird how no one noticed my mistake back in 2019 (including myself).. :/ Thanks for the fix. And how it also works for \$i^0\$ I guess, even though it's a bonus instead of necessity. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 7 bytes - 15 = -8

Port of [@blutorange's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26465/blutorange) devious [Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47446/95792). Go upvote that!

```scala
1->_*90
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUM1VlpijkGal4JSZ7pKanJkL5NnaKWh45pXoIIQ0FWz/G@raxWtZGvwvKMrMK8nJ00jTMNTU5ELwjFB4uYklGXoBmShiuqZAbu1/AA)

Takes a `BigDecimal` as input, outputs `(Int,BigDecimal)`, but honestly, you could make it work for any type with a `*` method.

### Crazier solution, 3 bytes - 15 = -12

```scala
90*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vcm9CsIwFMXxvU9xxlbUquCgoiC4Cg6@wG1zQyNpEpLrB4jPHh1E7HZ@559aspR9c@FWcCTjwA9hpxL2IeBZ3MhCr3Hw18YytrvfyqvZKG9Q12ePxIEiCcMIdPQ9QjROrBvDeYFjVqzgpeN4N4mLby11Oa@qPy0G6km66ckMvsnyw1d@Aw)

First component is assumed to be 1, so it only returns the second.

### Boring solution, <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```scala
" 1 i-1-i"drop _%4*2 take 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBCsIwEAXQfU/xKQiJEGiKK7EFly668gAytomMhiSkQxHEs0ff/q0zBarp/nSzYCKOcG9xcVlxzhmfZqMAf8QlCoYRVykcHxhqCws21nC7lJRx2x32PYReDn31qUAxTgYdJMF2GvnfJETlFWvdfOsP)

Answer (score 3):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [13 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn) - 5 = 8

```
◄š<f5®…┘┤ï\Î±
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=WzEiaSJuXzEiLWkiXT8lNA==&input=LTQKLTMKLTIKLTEKMQoyCjMKNA==)

## Explained

Unpacked: `[1"i"n_1"-i"]?%4`

```
  [        Begin sequence
    1      Literal one
    "i"    String
    n_     Negate
      1
    "-i"
  ]        End sequence
?          Indexed by
    _      Variable initialized to STDIN; implied
  %        Modulo
    4      Literal four
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), (<s>14</s> 11 bytes - 5) = 6

*Edit: -3 bytes thanks to Razetime*

```
!C2¨¹-1-i 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8b@is9GhFYd26hrqZioY/v//P1rXSEfXUMdAx1DHSMdYxyQWAA)

Comment: you can remove the `%4⁰`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), (30 bytes - 15) = 15

```
m₁m*1.57Ṡe-1
Σz*İ_m§/Π`^⁰↑99İ1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUYAuf9odXNr/20oLzEwMMO3MSoxMDAp4oKB/23igoJtKjEuNTfhuaBlLTEKzqN6KsSwX23Cpy/OoGBe4oGw4oaROTnEsDH///81)

(The header in TIO rounds the rational number output into a fraction with maximum 3-digit numerator & demominator, for readability)

Calculations with real numbers are a bit ticky in [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), since it doesn't have any trigonometric functions.  So here I implement -sin(x) as `` Σz*İ_m§/Π`^⁰↑99İ1 `` (99 iterations of the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Series_definition)), and use `1.57` as a very rough approximation for pi/2.

To make matters even more difficult, [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) natively outputs rational numbers as fractions, rather than decimals.  So there aren't any 'floating point' inaccuracies (but there are, of course, inaccuracies!).  The byte-count to round-away the (non-floating-point) inaccuracies for integer inputs is currently not included in the score.  Add [+10 bytes](https://tio.run/##AUEAvv9odXNr//9tyK8vMTDDtzEqMTBt4oKBbSoxLjU34bmgZS0xCs6jeirEsF9twqcvzqBgXuKBsOKGkTk5xLAx////NQ) to include it.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby 32-5=27

```
puts(%w[1 i -1 -i][gets.to_i%4])
```

Works for negative powers!

Comment: You can trivially golf this more with `puts %w[1 i -1 i][gets.to_i % 4]`.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 26 - 5 = 21

```
say qw(1 i -1 -i)[pop()%4]
```

works as a standalone program (argument on the commandline) or the body of a function.

Answer (score 2):

### Python - 31

```
print[1,'i',-1,'-i'][input()%4]
```

I have only recently started learning python. Even though I know it's not good, it's the best I can do.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell GHCi, 29 Bytes - 15 = 14

```
i p=[cos(p*pi/2),sin(p*pi/2)]
```

Usage:

```
*Main> i 0
[1.0,0.0]
*Main> i pi
[0.22058404074969779,-0.9753679720836315]
*Main> i (-6.4)
[-0.8090169943749477,0.5877852522924728]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 - 20 = -18 bytes

```
ı*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///IRq3///@b6hkDAA)

It doesn't use an `i ^ x` builtin but it uses builtins for `1j` and `**` so not sure if allowed.

Comment: *"If your language supports complex numbers, don't use any functions or arithmetic that could work this out."* I think it's pretty clear...

Comment: @totallyhuman Well, I'm not sure if the `1j` *literal* is banned either though?

Comment: Yeah, but the arithmetic (`*`) is.

Comment: @totallyhuman Hm, maybe I'll add another version below, although "don't use any functions or arithmetic that could work this out" seems to suggest that I can't use a built-in to do this exact task...BTW the way he phrases it gets me to think that you're *encouraged* to use `1j` literals.

Answer (score 2):

### Swift, 27

```
{["1","i","-1","-i"][$0%4]}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@Z@TWqKQbKWg4ZlXoqmga6cQXFKUmZeuYPu/OlrJUElHKROIdUEM3Uyl2GgVA1WT2Nr/GgZ6enqGBpp6aflFronJGQrVCgVAbSUayRoqBpqaCrX/AQ)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 19 bytes - 5 = 14

```perl6
{<1 i -1 -i>[$_%4]}
```

The result of `%` has the same sign as the divisor in this language.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZm@7/axlAhU0HXUEE30y5aJV7VJLb2vzVXWn6Rgo2BgpGCqYIhUMrY2E5B105BJU@hmouzOLFSQQnIBApUp2mo5GnWKnHV/gcA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 30 bytes

```c
f(x){printf(L"iㄭ椭1"+x%4);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9No0KzuqAoM68kTcNHKfNxy9pnS9YaKmlXqJpoWtf@z03MzNPQrOZKyy/SAKpRyLQ1sM60MQQS2tpAYQWFNI1MTeuC0pJiDSUlTWuuWq7a/wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 44 bytes -15=29

```c
#define f(x)cos(x*acos(0))+1i*sin(x*acos(0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYvLCsIwFET3/YqhIuT2IXbhqvZP3MQ0t1xI05IqFKS/bkx1IwwczjBj6sGYGA@9ZfEWrFYy06LWQu84E5WNFIv4vyaOOjm9MoCnoNBPz7uzEHSoL23iFTvK7tSAsM@AOYh/sEJ@ZHxz83kFqWCC1U6xEqIkMurhJ6A2Hbdsi2/DTg9LrN34AQ)

Handles signed and noninteger arguments.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), (29 bytes -15) = 14

```r
cos(m<-scan()*pi/2)+sin(m)*1i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pzm/WCPXRrc4OTFPQ1OrIFPfSFO7ODNPI1dTyzDzv64Rl64hl66eKZcBF5Aw5DLiMuYy4TLl@g8A)

Conventional complex number output; works for negative and real inputs.

(for completeness, there is also `c(1,scan()*90)` for a score of -1, using [blutorange's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47446/95126) <s>dubious</s> inventive polar output format in degrees)

Comment: Based on "(this bonus includes the -5 from the above bonus)", I don't think you can include both the -5 and -15 bonuses

Comment: @EthanChapman Ah, yes, you're right.  Fixed.  I was wondering why nobody else had such a good bonus...

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```rust
fn main() {
	// closure:
	// |n:usize|["1","i","-1","-i"][n%4]
	
	// call with: 
	print!("{}", (|n:usize|["1","i","-1","-i"][n%4])(3));	
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09DU6Gai1NfXyE5J7@4tCjVCsypybMqLc6sSq2JVjJU0lHKBGJdEEM3Uyk2Ok/VJJaLE6IpMSdHoTyzJMNKgYuzoCgzr0RRQ6m6VklHQYOgEZoaxpqa1pxctf//AwA)

The closure itself:

```rust
|n:usize|["1","i","-1","-i"][n%4]
```

Comment: You should probably put a version without comments and whitespace here as well, so it's easier to see what the actual 34 byte program is.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 29 bytes - 5 = 24

```
f n=words"1 i -1 -i"!!mod n 4
```

Works for negative powers.

I had a pointfree version worked out, but it turns out it's actually longer.

```
f=(words"1 i -1 -i"!!).(`mod`4)
```

Answer (score 1):

### C 105, was 117

```
char c[2];
int main()
{
int n,i,j=0;scanf("%d",&n);i=n%4;
i>1?c[j++]='-':c[j+1]='\0';
c[j]=i&1?'i':'1';
puts(c);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't even compile because you must parenthesize the assignments after `:` in `?:` statements in plain C. Also, what's the point of using `0==0` when you can use single char `1`? And no need in parentheses before `?`. Also, the last `?:` statement could be shortened to `c[j]=i&1?'i':'1';`.

Comment: @Ruslan In CodeBlocks Mingw there is only 1 warning around i&0. i&0==0 is a test for even, if i is even the result is 0 else it is 1.

Comment: Yeah, but what's the point of using `0==0` when it's identical to `1`? Note that `==` has higher precedence than `&`, otherwise your (supposed) test of `(i&0)==0` would always be true.

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure (<s>64</s> <s>54</s> 31 chars)

```
(defn i2n[n](println(case(mod n 4) 1 "i" 2 "-1" 3 "-i" 0 "1")))
```

### Edit

Per @SeanAllred's suggestion, here's a version which uses a literal vector instead of a `case` function:

```
(defn i2n[n](println (["1" "i" "-1" "-i"] (mod n 4))))
```

### Edit 2

By counting on the REPL to print out the resultant collection and coding the function using the `#()` shortcut we can reduce it to

```
#(["1" "i" "-1" "-i"](mod % 4))
```

(Which is actually much more Clojure/Lisp-ish as the function now actually returns the generated result, allowing the function to be used with `map`, as in

```
(map #(["1" "i" "-1" "-i"](mod % 4)) [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8])
```

which prints

```
("1" "i" "-1" "-i" "1" "i" "-1" "-i" "1")
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Instead of using a select structure, can't you use some sort of explicit array as in [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41808/7658)?

Answer (score 1):

## C# 63-5 = 58

public string m(int n)=>n%2==0?(n%4==0?"1":"-1"):(m(n-1)+"i");

Comment: output is in form -1i, 1i, i, or 1

Comment: You cannot claim the -15 bonus as this would fail on the input `3.247104`. You may only claim the -5 bonus.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes - I didn't read the bonuses bit properly

Comment: I have asked a question on meta about this answer: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4851/are-c-linqpad-answers-encouraged

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy: 27-5 = 22

```
f={n->[1,'i',-1,'-i'][n%4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 208 - 15 = 193

```
p=Math::PI/2;t=gets.to_f*p;l=->n{Math::cos(n).round(2)};k=l.call(t);if k!=0;k=k.to_i if k.abs==1;print k;end;m=l.call(t+p);if m!=0;r="i";r='-'+r if m==-1;r="#{m}"+r if 1>m && -1<m;r=" + "+r if k!=0;puts r end
```

This implementation completely conforms to the spec! 1.0 is written as 1, -1.0i is written as -i, etc. I don't see any other solution that incorporates this along with supporting floating points, except for maybe the TI-Calculator.

Ungolfed:

```
p=Math::PI/2
t=gets.to_f*p
l=->n{Math::cos(n).round(2)}

k=l.call(t)
if k!=0
  k=k.to_i if k.abs==1
  print k
end

m=l.call(t+p)
if m!=0
  r="i"
  r='-'+r if m==-1
  r="#{m}"+r if 1>m && -1<m
  r=" + "+r if k!=0
  puts r
end
```

Comment: `l.call(t)` → `l[t]`. Read [Tips for golfing in Ruby](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby) for more.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 61

```c
main(n){scanf("%d",&n);printf("%c%c",n%4/2*45,n%4%2?'i':49);}
```

Try it [here](http://ideone.com/ApUzPc).

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 26 - 5 = 21

```
n->Str([1,I,-1,-I][n%4+1])
```

`n->cos(t=Pi*n/2)+I*sin(t)` is one character shorter, but doesn't handle exact answers. Of course `n->I^n` is disallowed, and presumably also PARI's `powIs`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 39 bytes

```java
n->new String[]{"1","i","-1","-i"}[n%4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1Ba4NAEIXv/oqHUNAmLgTak0mOhR56yjHksDUqY9fZZXdMCcHfbldND8Mb3nvzTadvurCu5u76M1HvrBd00VODkFHNwJWQZfVaJm74NlShMjoEfGliPBLg6QbREuVm6Yo@ZtlJPHF7vkD7NuRLFfh44vafLHVb@y3W2hENDhMXR65/8X/5SHfpNqU4xbwUlI5nfnm7TDOpXHiN9ciIBYQDdmWUPd6jbDb5kq9fgdM9SN0rO4hyES6Gs0Zp58w9ozxfWWMyzzj9AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 27 bytes

```hs
(cycle(words"1 i -1 -i")!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBEkAgGAbQq3ysalHDyqobsLLEoknRCE0xxuX93lt13mwI5NRIzLwmWPacac5lDQ9RQ/iSFwWnXfsDCruOHVi8r/5K7QEJxzFUUjYTfcYFvWQSJsYf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 50 bytes

```
proc I n {expr $n%4==3?"-i":$n%4==2?-1:$n%4?"i":1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFTIU@hOrWioEhBJU/VxNbW2F5JN1PJCsIxstc1BDPtlYBihrX/SzJzUxWqC0pLihWUMuOiM/OSixTyYm2jPYG6Y5UUahWMDP4DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
®sfgm¹Éi1'i:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0LritPTcQzsPd2Yaqmda/f9vAgA)

---

```
®             # Push -1 onto the stack.
 sfg          # Push the number of prime factors of input.
    m         # -1^(number_prime_factors)
     ¹Éi      # is input even?
        1'i:  # if input was even, replace 1 with i.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 53 bytes - 5 bytes (bonus) = 48 bytes

```forth
: f 4 mod dup 1 > if ." -"then 2 mod 56 * '1 + emit ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7NCoMwEITvfYoPL4WWCNqfQy0@SS9BE02pSUgipU9vox6WZdiZb1a7kEYx6HUtywPNlcn19LOnosVoygJRpFFZ6u10u3PiWHFGTSbR5FT21og8vcNwoQxrCtFSZL0Ta54rrSJ62anIRjS5sAt8nPM0vHjPMaGl7X7klyaZkrEDxiJ3T3LE0X0JKs6fFA9@@QM)

This works for both positive and negative numbers

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f             \ start a new word definition
  4 mod dup     \ get result of n % 4 (and make a copy)
  1 > if        \ if result is 2 or 3
    ." -'       \ print a minus sign
  then          \ end the if
  2 mod 56 *    \ get result modulo 2 and multiply by 56 (difference between ascii for '1' and 'i')
  '1 +          \ add to ascii value of '1'
  emit          \ output the character for the given value
;               \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 30 bytes, score 25 (-5)

```sh
a=({,}{,-}{1,i})
<<<$a[$1%4+5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgAAXAvacQMlBS0D60yE4SLYQMhaiFRZB49tfMlwLeEA9POWeVEBPdLriZZ1myVCUbGYsg1lrmFmbqvhlWpBD3mzxn8jd1ZLtOD2i0GNFpDWWgxh8)

Based on the bash answer, but with some changes needed:

- `%4` results in a value in the range -3 to 3 (negative inputs give negative outputs), so we shift up with `+5`.
- Arrays are 1-indexed, hence `+5` instead of `+4`.
- We make our array twice as long by using brace expansion: `{,}foo` expands to `foo foo`.

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 32-15=17

- Input is in A1
- B1: `A1/2*PI(`
- Result: `=COMPLEX(COS(B1),SIN(B1`

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 - 5 = 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü▲τ}εT├?á
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=811ee77dee54c33fa0&i=4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Branch](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/branch-lang/), 38 bytes

```
^\4^%/;c1^>/0c45^?[.0]anc2^%/49c105^?.
```

Try it on the [online Branch interpreter](https://branch.hyper-neutrino.xyz/#WyJeXFw0XiUvO2MxXj4vMGM0NV4/Wy4wXWFuYzJeJS80OWMxMDVePy4iLCIiLCI1Il0=)!

### Explanation

```
      Implicit - the initial node's value is set to the first argument
^\4   Create a parent and sibling and set the right child to 4
%     Modulo
/;    Go to the left child and copy the mod result
c1    Go to the right child (automatically assigned register C) and set it to 1
^     Return to the parent (the mod result)
>     1 if the mod result is greater than 1, 0 otherwise
/0    Go to the left child and set to 0
c45   Go to the right child and set it to 45 (codepoint for "-")
^     Return to the parent
?     Conditional - if the mod was greater, go to the right child (45), and left child (0) otherwise
[  ]  While the value isn't 0
 .    Output it
  0   And set it to zero (this is basically an if statement)
an    Go to the left child and load the first argument (register N by default)
c2    Go to the right child and set it to 2
%     Modulo
/49   Go to the left child and set it to 49 (codepoint for "1")
c105  Go to the right child and set it to 105 (codepoint for "i")
^     Go to the parent
?     Conditional - if the exponent was even, go left, otherwise, go right
.     Output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 33 - 5 = 28 bytes

```lua
print(({1,'i',-1,'-i'})[...%4+1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDo9pQRz1TXUcXSOlmqtdqRuvp6amaaBvGav7//1/XEAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), <s>75</s> 57 bytes, no bonus

```go
func(n int)string{return[]string{"1","i","-1","-i"}[n%4]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCoMwEETv@YplQUhQS8Weav2H3tVDsEaW4irp6kXy7TaVHmaYGZg3zsdi@7cdB5gssVI0LbOXC7pJUKnNenBQH27lXjMQi/mIJx53P8jquen@FQvMkKLyX8gJQ8PJrQvn80RrA7tyswe619cK6FEU0dM0rs@IEKcxKV@tJOXWMmZAGThNxqigwvEF)

`if n<0{n=4+n}` is included here because the `%` operator in Go returns negative if the dividend is negative.

Comment: At the moment, this qualifies for a -5 bonus (since it handles negative numbers too), so your score is 70 bytes. But, if you don't go for any bonuses, you can get this down to [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYzBCoMwEETv@xXLgpCgloo91foPvauHYI0sxVXS6EXy7TaVHmaYGZg3zsdi@rcZB5wMCwBPy@z8hezkCWAzDi3Wh12lV4IsXn@8Yxl3cINfnTTdv1NBGXFU/gs5U2gkuXXhvJ5spXEHOzvke32tkB9FET1N4/qMCG8VJeWr9Um5tUIZcoZWsdYQIBxf "Go – Try It Online")

Comment: You can also remove the redundant newline for [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYzBCoMwEETv@YplQUhQS8Weav2H3tVDsEaW4irp6kXy7TaVHmaYGZg3zsdi@7cdB5gssVI0LbOXC7pJUKnNenBQH27lXjMQi/mIJx53P8jquen@FQvMkKLyX8gJQ8PJrQvn80RrA7tyswe619cK6FEU0dM0rs@IEKcxKV@tJOXWMmZAGThNxqigwvEF)

Answer (score 0):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 15 - 5 = 10 bytes

```
1i0;`-i`¿4%⊙&ø&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fMNPAOkE3M@HQfhPVR10z1Q7vUPv/3wgA)

Pushes the four different possibilities and then takes the input modulo 4 and indexes the stack.

Comment: You program supports negative numbers, you should have the -5 bonus! ```-5 if you can work the value out where n is also negative```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `r`, 5 - 15 = -10 bytes

```
90*1"
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=90*1%22&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

Well if the Ruby answer's output method is valid, so is this. Outputs in "polar form (angular unit: degrees)".

### Explained

```
90*1"
90*   # Multiply the input by 90
   1" # Push one and pair the two inputs. The `-r` flag makes dyads take their arguments in reverse.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 10 - 5 = 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
`-iu'i1K$i
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWqxJ0M0vVMw29VTKXFCclF0OFFyzSNYawAA)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
`-iu'i1K$i  '# Implicit input
`-i          # Push the string "-i"
   u         # Push the number -1
    'i      '# Push the string "i"
      1      # Push the number 1
       K     # Wrap the stack into a list
             # -> [1, "i", -1, "-i"]
        $i   # Index the input in
             # (0-based, modular)
             # Implicit output
```