# Extendify the ASCII Sun

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Write a program that takes in (via STDIN/command line) a non-negative integer N.

When N is 0, your program should print `O` (that's capital Oh, not zero).

When N is 1, your program should print

```
\|/
-O-
/|\
```

When N is 2 your program should print

```
\ | /
 \|/
--O--
 /|\
/ | \
```

When N is 3 your program should print

```
\  |  /
 \ | /
  \|/
---O---
  /|\
 / | \
/  |  \
```

For larger N, this pattern continues on in the same exact fashion. Each of the eight rays of the "sun" should be made of N of the appropriate `-`, `|`, `/`, or `\` characters.

### Details

- Instead of a program, you may write a function that takes an integer. The function should print the sun design normally or return it as a string.
- You must either

  - have no trailing spaces at all, or
  - only have enough trailing spaces so the pattern is a perfect (2N+1)*(2N+1) rectangle.
- The output for any or all N may optionally have a trailing newline.

### Scoring

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Is a leading newline allowed? Especially interesting for `N=0`.

Comment: @Jakube No. Trailing only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>39</s> <s>38</s> 36 bytes

```
jbXmXXj\|m*\ Q2d\\_hd\/JhyQQX*\-JQ\O
```

Try it online: [Pyth Compiler/Executor](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jbXmXXj%5C%7Cm*%5C+Q2d%5C%5C_hd%5C%2FJhyQQX*%5C-JQ%5CO&input=3&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
jbXmXXj\|m*\ Q2d\\_hd\/JhyQQX*\-JQ\O   implicit: Q = input
                       JhyQ            J = 1 + 2*Q
    m                  J               map each d of [0,1,...,2*Q] to:
          *\ Q                           " "*input
         m    2                          list with twice " "*input
      j\|                                join this list by "|"
     X         d\\                       replace the value at d to "\"
    X             _hd\/                  replace the value at -(d+1) to "/"
  X                        Q           replace line Q by:
                             *\-J        "-"*J
                            X    Q\O     replace element at Q with "O"
jb                                     join by "newlines"
```

Another 36 bytes solution would be:

```
jbmXXj\|m*?\-KqdQ\ Q2d\\_hd?\OK\/hyQ
```

Answer (score 26):

## C: <s>116</s> <s>102</s> <s>99</s> <s>95</s> <s>92</s> 90

```c
s(n){for(int c=-n,r=c;r<=n;c++)putchar(c>n?c=-c,r++,10:c?r?c-r?c+r?32:47:92:45:r?124:79);}
```

I think that I am getting fairly close to a minimal solution using this approach, but I can't stop feeling that there is a much better approach in C. Ungolfed:

```c
void s(int n) {
  for(
    int c = -n, r = c;
    r <= n;
    c++
  )
    putchar(
      c > n
        ? c = -c, r++, '\n'
        : c
          ? r
            ? c - r
              ? c + r
                ? ' '
                : '/'
              : '\\'
            : '-'
          : r
            ? '|'
            : 'O'
    );
}
```

Comment: "c++" in C ... heh!

Comment: I'm glad you ungolfed it. Those ternary ifs are insane!

Comment: You can save 2 more bytes and make it vc 2012 compliant ;) `c,r;s(n){for(r=c=-n;r<=n;c++)putchar(c>n?c=-c,r++,10:c?r?c-r?c+r?32:47:92:45:r?124:79);}`

Answer (score 21):

## GNU sed, 252 + 1

Phew - I beat the php answer!

Score + 1 for using the `-r` parameter.

Because of sed limitations, we have to burn nearly 100 bytes just convert N to a string of N spaces.  The rest is the fun stuff.

```
/^0/{y/0/O/;q}
s/./<&/g
s/9/8 /g
s/8/7 /g
s/7/6 /g
s/6/5 /g
s/5/4 /g
s/4/3 /g
s/3/2 /g
s/2/1 /g
s/1/ /g
s/0//g
:t
s/ </<          /g
tt
s/<//g
:
s/ //
s^.*^\\&|&/^;ta
:a
/\\$/q
p
s^\\\|/^-O-^;tn
s^(\\)? (/)?^\2 \1^g;ta
:n
y/ /-/
p
s^-O-^/|\\^
y/-/ /
ta
```

#### Explanation

- The first line is an early exit for the N=0 case.
- The next 15 lines (up to the `:`) convert N to a string of N spaces
- `s/ //` removes one space
- `s^.*^\\&|&/^;ta` converts N-1 spaces to: `\` + N-1 spaces + `|` + N-1 spaces + `/`
- Iterate, printing each iteration, and moving `\` one space to the right and `/` one space to the left...
- ...until we match `\|/`, which is replaced with `-O-` and jump to the `n` label
- replace  with `-` and print
- replace `-0-` with `/|\`, and replace  with `-` and jump back into the main loop
- Iterate, printing each iteration, and moving `\` one space to the right and `/` one space to the left...
- ...until we match `\$` which indicates were finished, and quit.

#### Output

```
 $ for i in {0..3}; do sed -rf asciisun.sed <<< $i ; done
 O
 \|/
 -O-
 /|\
 \ | /
  \|/ 
 --O--
  /|\ 
 / | \
 \  |  /
  \ | / 
   \|/  
 ---O---
   /|\  
  / | \ 
 /  |  \
 $
```

Answer (score 16):

## J, <s>37</s> <s>34</s> 40 bytes

```
1:echo('O\/-|'{.@#~0=+&|,-,+,[,])"*/~@i:
```

Usage:

```
   (1:echo('O\/-|'{.@#~0=+&|,-,+,[,])"*/~@i:) 2  NB. prints to stdout:
\ | /
 \|/ 
--O--
 /|\ 
/ | \
```

Explanation (from left to right):

- `i:` generates list `-n, -(n-1), ..., n-1, n`
- `(  )"*/~@i:` creates the Descartes product of i: with itself in a matrix arrangement, e.g. for `n = 1` creates the following `3-by-3` matrix

  ```
  ┌─────┬────┬────┐
  │-1 -1│-1 0│-1 1│
  ├─────┼────┼────┤
  │0 -1 │0 0 │0 1 │
  ├─────┼────┼────┤
  │1 -1 │1 0 │1 1 │
  └─────┴────┴────┘
  ```
- for every matrix-element with integers `x y` we do the following
- `+&|,-,+,[,]` calculate a list of properties

  - `+&|` `abs(x)+abs(y)`, equals `0` iff (if and only if) `x=0` and `y=0`
  - `-` x-y, equals `0` iff `x=y` i.e. we are on the diagonal
  - `+` x+y, equals `0` iff `x=-y` i.e. we are on the anti-diagonal
  - `[` x, equals `0` iff `x=0` i.e. we are on the middle row
  - `]` y, equals `0` iff `y=0` i.e. we are on the middle column
- `'O\/-|'#~0=` compare these above property values to `0` and take the `i`th character from the string `'O\/-|'` if the `i`th property is true.
- the first character in the resulting string will always be the one we need, if there string is empty we need a space
- `{.` takes the first character of a string and if there is no one it returns a space character as padding just as we need
- we now have the exact matrix we need so we print it to stdout once with `1:echo`

[Try it online here.](http://tryj.tk/)

Comment: This is the ungolfed version?! I feel like a pretty average programmer at times, and then for some reason I end up on codegolf and see the stuff you guys pull off and can't help but feel like an idiot.

Comment: @JustSid Well, the text wasn't up to date with the code but technically I never wrote that the code is ungolfed. :)

Comment: It's still mighty impressive either way

Comment: @JustSid Not that it's any less impressive but J code pretty much just looks like that, and this seems like a challenge that it would be a good language for. It's a very impressive answer, but so is everything else in J :)

Answer (score 11):

## PHP, 182 bytes

This seemed like a fun activity for my first answer. Comments on my code are welcome.

```php
<?php function s($n){$e=2*$n+1;for($i=0;$i<$e*$e;$i++){$x=$i%$e;$y=floor($i/$e);echo$y==$x?($x==$n?"O":"\\"):($e-1==$x+$y?"/":($y==$n?"-":($x==$n?"|":" ")));echo$x==$e-1?"\n":"";}}?>
```

Here is the un-golfed code with comments:

```php
<?php
function s($n) {
    $e=2*$n+1; //edge length
    for($i=0;$i<$e*$e;$i++) {
        $x = $i%$e; // current x coordinate
        $y = floor($i/$e); // current y coordinate

        if ($y==$n&&$x==$n) {
            // center of square
            echo'O';
        }
        else if ($y==$n) {
            // horizontal line
            echo'-';
        }
        else if ($x==$n) {
            // vertical line
            echo'|';
        }
        else if ($y==$x) {
            // diagonal line from top-left to bottom right
            echo'\\';
        }
        else if (($y-$n)==($n-$x)) {
            // diagonal line from bottom-left to top-right
            echo'/';
        }
        else {
            // empty space
            echo' ';
        }
        if ($x==$e-1) {
            // add new line for the end of the row
            echo"\n";
        }
    }
}?>
<pre>
<?php s(10); ?>
</pre>
```

**Edited with code by royhowie**

Comment: Hi :-) Good first effort. You can shrink your code in quite a few places though. For example `if(($y-$h)==($x-$h))` does the same as `if(($y==$x)`. You can save another character by replacing `if($x==y$)foo();else bar();` with `if($x^$y)bar();else foo();`. You should also try using [ternary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) instead of `if .. else` statements.

Comment: ternary operators is a good tip

Comment: 174 bytes: `function s($n){$e=2*$n+1;for($i=0;$i<$e*$e;$i++){$x=$i%$e;$y=floor($i/$e);echo$y==$x?($x==$n?"O":"\\"):($e-1==$x+$y?"/":($y==$n?"-":($x==$n?"|":" ")));echo$x==$e-1?"\n":"";}}`

Comment: 1. there's no need for `$r`; just use `echo` (`$r.=` is the same amount of bytes as `echo`). 2. used ternary operator (saves a lot of characters). 3. `$h` was useless since it equaled `$n`. 4. You didn't need to use `floor` for `$x = floor($i%$e);`, since a modulus on an integer won't need to be rounded down.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I never thought of that. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @royhowie Thanks! Is it ok if I update my answer with your solution?

Comment: @user2518200 of course

Comment: With or without the `floor()` calls the $x and $y calculation still seems longer than using 2 `for`s. And when possible, combine calculation and first use – for example calculate $e inside the `for` where it is first used. Based on @royhowie's version, 161 characters: `function s($n){for($y=0;$y<$e=2*$n+1;$y++)for($x=0;$x<$e;){echo$y==$x?($x==$n?"O":"\\"):($e-1==$x+$y?"/":($y==$n?"-":($x==$n?"|":" ")));echo$x++==$e-1?"\n":"";}}`

Comment: Replace `floor($e/2);` with `$e>>1;` and you will save a few bytes.

Comment: `for(;$i<$c=1+2*$argn;$o.="$t\n"){$t=str_pad("|O"[$b=$i++==$argn],$c," -"[$b],2);$b?:$t[$i-1]="\\".!$t[$c-$i]="/";}echo$o;` 121 Bytes

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Wow that is nice. Feel free to make a new answer. I'll upvote it.

Comment: Feel free to take it as as your improvement.

Comment: I have reuse my idea in an other challenge so you can use it here

Answer (score 9):

### Python 2, 99

```python
n=input()
R=range(-n,n+1)
for i in R:print''.join("O\|/ -"[[R,i,0,-i,j].index(j)^(i==0)]for j in R)
```

Prints line by line, creating each line by checking whether the coordinate `(i,j)` (centered at `(0,0)`) satisfies `j==-i`, `j==0`, `j==i`, or none, with a hack to make the center line work.

Comment: I think you can use `R` instead of `.5` to save 1 byte.

Comment: @randomra That's clever, thanks. Down to two digits!

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, <s>48 45 43 41</s> 38 bytes

This is still too long and I am still doing some redundant things, but here goes:

```
ri:R{_S*"\|/"@R-~S**1$N}%'-R*'O1$W$sW%
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%3AR%7B_S*%22%5C%7C%2F%22%40R-%7ES**1%24N%7D%25%27-R*%27O1%24W%24sW%25&input=6)

Answer (score 7):

## SpecBAS - 117 bytes

```
1 INPUT s: LET t=s*2: FOR y=0 TO t: PRINT AT y,y;"\";AT y,t/2;"|";AT t-y,y;"/";AT t/2,y;"-": NEXT y: PRINT AT s,s;"O"
```

This prints the slashes and dashes in one loop, and then plonks the "O" in the middle.

Output using 1, 2 and 9

[image]

Comment: An anonymous user suggested to change `"-": NEXT y: PRINT AT s,s;"O"` to `"-";AT s,s;"O": NEXT y` to save two bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6) 97 <s>98</s>

This seems different enough ...

```js
// GOLFED
f=n=>(y=>{for(t='';++y<n;t+='\n')for(x=-n;++x<n;)t+='-O /\\|'[y?x?x-y?x+y?2:3:4:5:+!x]})(-++n)||t

// Ungolfed

F=n=>{
  ++n;
  t = '';
  for (y = -n; ++y < n; t += '\n')
    for (x = -n; ++x < n; )
      if (y != 0)
        if (x != 0)
          if (x != y)
            if (x != -y)
              t += ' '
            else
              t += '/'
          else
            t += '\\'
        else
          t += '|'
      else
        if (x != 0)
          t += '-'
        else 
          t += 'O'
  return t;
}
    
// TEST
function test(){ OUT.innerHTML = f(N.value|0); }
test()
```

```css
input { width: 4em }
```

```html
N: <input id=N value=5><button onclick="test()">Go</button>
<pre id="OUT"></pre>
```

Comment: Beautiful. I should have thought of a closure to use normal for loops.

Comment: I like this one. I had tried writing one using a string and accessing a specific index, but yours is much shorter.

Answer (score 7):

## OS/2 Classic Rexx, 102... or 14 for "cheater's version"

Take out the linefeeds to "golf" it.

```
w='%1'
o=center('O',w,'-')
m='center(space("\|/",w),%1)'
do w
  w=w-1
  interpret "o="m"|o|"m
end l
say o
```

Cheater's version, name the script whatever source code you want under 255 characters (requires HPFS disk):

```
interpret '%0'
```

---

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, cheater's version isn't intended to count! It's just to be silly and show an old dog can still do tricks. :)

*e.g. For real fun and games, an implementation of Java-8/C11 style "lambda" expressions on a list iterator. Not tested, but ought to run on a circa 1979 IBM mainframe. ;)*

```
ForEachInList( 'Months.January.Days', 'Day' -> 'SAY "You have an appointment with" Day.Appointment.Name "on" Day.Appointment.Date' )
EXIT

ForEachInList: 
    SIGNAL ON SYNTAX
    PARSE ARG MyList "," MyVar "->" MyCommand
    INTERPRET ' MyListCount = ' || MyList || '.Count'
    DO ListIndex = 1 TO MyListCount
       INTERPRET MyVar || ' = ' || MyList || '.' || ListIndex
       INTERPRET MyCommand
    END
    RETURN
SYNTAX:
    SAY MyCommand ' is not a valid expression. '
    EXIT
```

-- Calling code assumes you already made a stem (array), naturally.

Comment: For your cheater version: if the filename of a program is not arbitrary, [it has to be included in the byte count](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default#comment3902_1072).

Comment: Fair enough. Cheater's version wasn't intended as at all serious! :) ...which is why I posted the "real" answer at 102. It was just for novelty's sake.

Comment: @lisa except that its not novel at all ;) . Also, it would break the leaderboard script if used in this challenge.

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, <s>109</s> <s>98</s> 96 bytes

Thanks to nimi and Mauris for their help!

```
0#0='O'
0#_='-'
_#0='|'
i#j|i==j='\\'|i== -j='/'|1<2=' '
f n=unlines[map(i#)[-n..n]|i<-[-n..n]]
```

**Explanation:**

The operator `#` specifies which character appears at coordinates (i,j), with the sun centered at (0,0). Function `f` builds the result String by mapping `#` over all pairs of coordinates ranging from -n to n.

**Usage:**

```
ghci> putStr $ f 2
\ | /
 \|/ 
--O--
 /|\ 
/ | \
```

Comment: You can save a few bytes by using an infix operator instead of `s`, e.g. `0#0='O'`, `0#_='-'`, etc. and `1<2` instead of `True`.

Comment: Maybe `map(i#)[-n..n]` to save two bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>177</s> 149 bytes

Mickey T. is the man! He helped me fix my originally incorrect solution *and* save 28 bytes. Thanks, Mickey!

```r
m=matrix(" ",(w=2*(n=scan()+1)-1),w);m[row(m)==rev(col(m))]="/";diag(m)="\\";m[,n]="|";m[n,]="-";m[n,n]="O";m[,w]=paste0(m[,w],"\n");cat(t(m),sep="")
```

Ungolfed + explanation:

```r
# Create a matrix of spaces, read n from stdin, assign w=2n+1
m <- matrix(" ", (w <- 2*(n <- scan() + 1) - 1), w)

# Replace the opposite diagonal with forward slashes
m[row(m) == rev(col(m))] <- "/"

# Replace the diagonal with backslashes
diag(m) <- "\\"

# Replace the vertical center line with pipes
m[, n] <- "|"

# Replace the horizontal center line with dashes
m[n, ] <- "-"

# Put an O in the middle
m[n, n] <- "O"

# Collapse the columns into single strings
m[, w] <- paste0(m[, w], "\n")

# Print the transposed matrix
cat(t(m), sep = "")
```

Any further suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Sorry Alex, you missed the vertical rays.  There is a few things that could be changed to shorten this without changing the general process.  The `scan` doesn't really need the `w=`.  It can also be shifted deeper into the commands.  The `if` can be ditched if you change the way the matrix is handled in a couple of instances.  Applying these I get `m=matrix(" ",(w=2*(n=scan()+1)-1),w);m[row(m)-rev(col(m))==0]='/';diag(m)="\\";m[,n]='|';m[n,]="-";m[n,n]="O";m[,w]=paste0(m[,w],'\n');cat(t(m),sep='')`.  Further golfing possible I think.

Comment: @MickyT: That's fantastic. Thank you so much for noticing my mistake and proving a much better solution! I edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Rust, 215 characters

```rust
fn a(n:usize){for i in 0..n{println!("{}\\{}|{1}/{0}",s(i),s(n-i-1))}println!("{}O{0}",vec!["-";n].concat());for i in(0..n).rev(){println!("{}/{}|{1}\\{0}",s(i),s(n-i-1))}}fn s(n:usize)->String{vec![" ";n].concat()}
```

I tried to use a string slicing method (by creating a string of `n-1` spaces and slicing to and from an index) like so:

```rust
fn a(n:usize){let s=vec![" ";n-(n>0)as usize].concat();for i in 0..n{println!("{}\\{}|{1}/{0}",&s[..i],&s[i..])}println!("{}O{0}",vec!["-";n].concat());for i in(0..n).rev(){println!("{}/{}|{1}\\{0}",&s[..i],&s[i..])}}
```

But that's actually 3 chars longer.

Ungolfed code:

```rust
fn asciisun_ungolfed(n: usize) {
    for i in 0..n {
        println!("{0}\\{1}|{1}/{0}", spaces(i), spaces(n-i-1))
    }
    println!("{0}O{0}", vec!["-"; n].concat());
    for i in (0..n).rev() {
        println!("{0}/{1}|{1}\\{0}", spaces(i), spaces(n-i-1))
    }
}
fn spaces(n: usize) -> String { vec![" "; n].concat() }
```

The part I like is how I shave a few chars off on the formatting strings. For example,

```rust
f{0}o{1}o{1}b{0}ar
```

is equivalent to

```rust
f{}o{}o{1}b{0}ar
```

because the "auto-incrementer" for the format string argument position is not affected by manually specifying the number, and acts completely independently.

Answer (score 4):

## IDL 8.3, 135 bytes

Dunno if this can be golfed more... It's very straightforward. First we create a `m x m` array (`m=2n+1`) of empty strings; then, we draw the characters in lines (`y=x`, `y=-x`, `y=n`, and `x=n`). Then we drop the O in at point `(n, n)`, and print the whole thing, formatted as `m` strings of length 1 on each line so that there's no extra spacing from printing the array natively.

```
pro s,n
m=2*n+1
v=strarr(m,m)
x=[0:m-1]
v[x,x]='\'
v[x,m-x-1]='/'
v[n,x]='|'
v[x,n]='-'
v[n,n]='O'
print,v,f='('+strtrim(m,2)+'A1)'
end
```

Test:

```
IDL> s,4
\   |   /
 \  |  / 
  \ | /  
   \|/   
----O----
   /|\   
  / | \  
 /  |  \ 
/   |   \
```

Comment: "Instead of a program, you may write a function that takes an integer. The function should print the sun design normally or return it as a string."

Comment: hahaha no worries :)

Answer (score 4):

## C#, <s>230</s> 226 bytes

```cs
string g(int n){string r="";int s=n*2+1;for(int h=0;h<s;h++){for(int w=0;w<s;w++){if(h==w){if(w==n){r+="O";}else{r+="\\";}}else if(w==s-h-1){r+="/";}else if(w==n){r+="|";}else if(h==n){r+="-";}else{r+=" ";}}r+="\n";}return r;}
```

As requested, the ungolfed version:

    string ug(int n) {

```cs
        // The sting we'll be returning
        string ret = ""; 

        // The width and height of the output
        int s = n * 2 + 1; 

        // for loop for width and height
        for (int height = 0; height < s; height++) 
        {
            for (int width = 0; width < s; width++) 
            {
                // Matches on top-left to bottom-right diagonal line
                if (height == width) 
                {
                    // If this is the center, write the 'sun'
                    if (width == n) 
                    {
                        ret += "O"; 
                    }
                    // If this is not the center, add the diagonal line character
                    else 
                    {
                        ret += "\\"; 
                    }
                }
                // Matches on top-right to bottom-left diagonal line
                else if (width == s - height - 1) 
                { 
                    ret += "/";
                }
                // Matches to add the center line
                else if (width == n) 
                { 
                    ret += "|";
                }
                // Matches to add the horizontal line
                else if (height == n) 
                { 
                    ret += "-";
                }
                // Matches all others
                else 
                { 
                    ret += " "; 
                } 
            } 
            // Add a newline to separate each line
            ret += "\n"; 
        } 
        return ret; 
    }
```

This is my first post so apologies if I've done something wrong. Any comments and corrections are very welcome.

Comment: Also, `s=2*n+1` rather than `s=(n*2)+1` and `w==s-h-1` rather than `w==(s-h)-1` will make this a little shorter.

Comment: nice, may steal your string building method. it annoys me that linq is longer than for loops :(

Comment: I've added the ungolfed version :)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby: <s>98</s> 92 characters

Proc that returns a string with the Sun.

```ruby
f=->n{x=(0..m=n*2).map{|i|s=?|.center m+1
s[i]=?\\
s[m-i]=?/
s}
x[n]=?O.center m+1,?-
x*?\n}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> f=->n{x=(0..m=n*2).map{|i|s=?|.center m+1;s[i]=?\\;s[m-i]=?/;s};x[n]=?O.center m+1,?-;x*?\n}
=> #<Proc:0x000000020dea60@(irb):1 (lambda)>
irb(main):002:0> (0..3).each {|i| puts f[i]}
O
\|/
-O-
/|\
\ | /
 \|/ 
--O--
 /|\ 
/ | \
\  |  /
 \ | / 
  \|/  
---O---
  /|\  
 / | \ 
/  |  \
=> 0..3
```

Answer (score 4):

## Octave 85

Bulding matrices as always=)
`eye` produces an identity matrix, the rest is self explanatory I think.

```
m=(e=eye(2*(k=input('')+1)-1))*92+rot90(e)*47;m(:,k)='|';m(k,:)=45;m(k,k)='o';[m,'']
```

Comment: Still two bytes better than mine :( I actually tried something similar to this initially, but couldn't get it small enough - I didn't realize I could do "m(:,k)='|'". Nice submission!

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (*ES7 Draft*) 115

```js
f=l=>[['O |/\\-'[y^x?z+~x^y?y^l?x^l?1:2:5:3:x^l&&4]for(x in _)].join('')for(y in _=[...Array(z=2*l+1)])].join('\n')


// Snippet demo: (Firefox only)
for(var X of [0,1,2,3,4,5])
    document.write('<pre>' + f(X) + '</pre><br />');
```

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab, <s>93</s> 87 bytes

Sadly the function header has to be so big...
Apart from that I think it is golfed pretty well. I wonder if it could be done better with some of the syntax differences in Octave.

```
N=input('');E=eye(N)*92;D=rot90(E)*.52;H=ones(1,N)*45;V=H'*2.76;[E V D;H 79 H;D V E '']
```

Comment: You can just make a program with `N=input('')` to save 2 characters. Other than that you can just write `[E V D;H 79 H;D V E '']` for converting the whole matrix into a char array, which will save you another byte or two. ( I just submitted an Octave program with a slightly different approach, but before I found yours=)

Comment: I actually had the input line first, but for some reason I mistakenly thought it wasn't allowed... Thanks for the other tip though!

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 52 bytes

The hard part was figuring out how to switch the slashes for each side. I settled for defining a lambda that takes the symbols to use.

```
KdMms[*Kt-QdG*Kd\|*KdH)_UQjbg\\\/p\O*Q\-*\-Qjb_g\/\\
```

Can likely be golfed more, explanation coming soon.

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=KdMms%5B*Kt-QdG*Kd%5C%7C*KdH)_UQjbg%5C%5C%5C%2Fp%5CO*Q%5C-*%5C-Qjb_g%5C%2F%5C%5C&input=3).

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 94

There are a lot of nested ternary operators in here, but I think the code is reasonably straightforward.

```
$n=<>;for$x(-$n..$n){for$y(-$n..$n){print$x^$y?$x+$y?$x?$y?$":'|':'-':'/':$x?'\\':'O'}print$/}
```

**Try it out here:** [ideone.com/E8MC1d](http://ideone.com/E8MC1d)

Comment: 88B: `for$x(-($n=<>)..$n){map{print$x^$_?$x+$_?$x?$_?$":'|':'-':'/':$x?'\\':O}-$n..$n;print$/}` - A couple of tweaks: convert inner for to map and change $y to $_; inline `($n=<>)`.

Answer (score 2):

**C# - 291 (full program)**

```
using System;using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(string[] a){Func<int,int,int,char>C=(s,x,i)=>x==(2*s+1)?'\n':i==s?x==s?'O':'-':x==s?'|':x==i?'\\':x==2*s-i?'/':' ';int S=int.Parse(a[0])*2;Console.Write(Enumerable.Range(0,(S+1)*(S+1)+S).Select(z=>C(S/2,z%(S+2),z/(S+2))).ToArray());}}
```

Comment: working on it!!

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 80 bytes

```hs
a#b=2*a+0^b^2
f n|r<-[-n..n]=[[" /\\x-xOx|"!!mod(0#x#y#(x-y)#(x+y))9|x<-r]|y<-r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E5ydZIK1HbIC4pzogrTSGvpshGN1o3T08vL9Y2OlpJQT8mpkK3wr@iRklRMTc/RcNAuUK5UlmjQrdSE0hqV2pqWtZU2OgWxdZUgsj/uYmZeQq2CrmJBb7xCgWlJcElRT55ChppCiaa/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <strike>139</strike> <strike>135</strike> 140 + 1 bytes

(+1 is for `-p` flag with node in the console)

**fixed:**

```js
t=(n,m)=>(m=2*n+1,(A=Array).from(A(m),(d,i)=>A.from(A(m),(e,j)=>i==j?j==n?"O":"\\":m-1==j+i?"/":i==n?"-":j==n?"|":" ").join("")).join("\n"))
```

**usage:**

```js
t(3)
/*
\  |  /
 \ | / 
  \|/  
---O---
  /|\  
 / | \ 
/  |  \
*/
```

**ungolfed:**

```js
var makeSun = function (n, m) {
    m = 2 * n + 1;    // there are 2*n+1 in each row/column
    return Array.from(Array(m), function (d, i) {
        return Array.from(Array(m), function (e, j) {
            // if i is j, we want to return a \
            // unless we're at the middle element
            // in which case we return the sun ("O")
            if (i == j) {
                return j == n ? "O" : "\\";
            // the other diagonal is when m-1 is j+i
            // so return a forward slash, /
            } else if (m - 1 == j + i) {
                return "/";
            // the middle row is all dashes
            } else if (i == n) {
                return "-";
            // the middle column is all pipes
            } else if (j == n) {
                return "|";
            // everything else is a space
            } else {
                return " ";
            }
        }).join("");
    }).join("\n");
}
```

Comment: You appear to be missing two rays.

Comment: Oh, darn, I forgot to add that back in…

Comment: `(A=Array).from(A(m))`

Comment: @MichaelT I fixed it, but I think I can golf it some more

Comment: @Shmiddty thanks for the suggestion! that saved a lot of characters

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby - 130 bytes

```
def f(n);a=(0...n).map{|i|' '*i+"\\"+' '*(n-1-i)+'|'+' '*(n-1-i)+'/'+' '*i};puts(a+['-'*n+'O'+'-'*n]+a.reverse.map(&:reverse));end
```

usage:

```
irb(main):002:0> f(3)
\  |  /
 \ | /
  \|/
---O---
  /|\
 / | \
/  |  \
```

Comment: Applied a couple of old trick: `f=->n{a=(0...n).map{|i|(s=' ')*i+?\\+s*(m=n-1-i)+?|+s*(m)+?/+s*i};puts(a+[?-*n+'O'+?-*n]+a.reverse.map(&:reverse))}` (See [Tips for golfing in Ruby](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby) for some more.)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl <s>85</s> <s>91</s> <s>90</s> <s>89</s> 86B

```pl
map{$_=$r||O;s/^|$/ /mg;s/ (-*O-*) /-$1-/;$r="\\$s|$s/
$_
/$s|$s\\";$s.=$"}1..<>;say$r
```

Ungolfed:

```pl
# usage: echo 1|perl sun.pl

map {
    $_ = $r || O;  # no strict: o is "o". On the first run $r is not defined
    s/^|$/ /mg;    # overwriting $_ saves characters on these regexes
    s/ (-*O-*) /-$1-/;
    $r = "\\$s|$s/
$_
/$s|$s\\";         # Embedded newlines save 1B vs \n. On the first run $s is not defined.
    $s .= $"
} 1..<>;
say $r
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>175 129 127</s> 125 Bytes

```python
s,q,x=' ','',int(input())
for i in range(x):d=(x-i-1);q+=(s*i+'\\'+s*d+'|'+s*d+'/'+s*i+'\n')
print(q+'-'*x+'O'+'-'*x+q[::-1])
```

Try it online [here](http://repl.it/nHv/1).

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>193</s> 186 bytes

#### Golfed

```
def f(n):
 s,b,e,d,g=' \\/|-';p,r,i='',int(n),0
 while r:print(s*i+b+s*(r-1)+d+s*(r-1)+e);r-=1;i+=1
 print(g*n+'O'+g*n);r+=1;i=n-1
 while r<n+1:print(s*i+e+s*(r-1)+d+s*(r-1)+b);r+=1;i-=1
```

#### Output

```
>>> f(3)
\  |  /
 \ | /
  \|/
---O---
  /|\
 / | \
/  |  \

>>> f(5)
\    |    /
 \   |   /
  \  |  /
   \ | /
    \|/
-----O-----
    /|\
   / | \
  /  |  \
 /   |   \
/    |    \
```

#### Ungolfed

```
def f(n):
    s, b, e, d, g = ' \\/|-'
    p, r, i = '', int(n), 0
    while r:
        print(s*i + b + s*(r-1) + d + s*(r-1) + e)
        r -= 1
        i += 1
    print(g*n + 'O' + g*n)
    r += 1
    i = n-1
    while r < n+1:
        print(s*i + e + s*(r-1) + d + s*(r-1) + b)
        r += 1
        i -= 1
```

Comment: There's a few things to be golfed here, but the biggest one is your default arguments. `s=' ',b='\\',f='/',d='|',g='-'` is *very* long, so you'd be better off moving it by adding `s,b,f,d,g=" \/|-"` to the second line.

Comment: I meant `" \/|-"` as a single string, rather than splitting it up into individual chars. You can unpack from a string like `x,y,z="123"`, which makes `x="1"`, `y="2"` and `z="3"`.

Comment: Edited again. Thanks @Sp3000

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, <s>59</s> 55 bytes

```
ri:A,W%{_S*"\|/"\*\A\-(S*_@@++}%_Wf%W%['-A*_'O\++]\++N*
```

This won't win any awards as-is but I was happy enough it worked!

Thanks to Sp3000 for golfing tips.

Comment: Nice work! Here's a few tips: 1) You can use `S` instead of the `'` version for space and 2) For `'-A*'O'-A` you can do ``'-A*_'O\`` instead because generating it twice is long

Answer (score 1):

## Prolog, 219 bytes

No, it's not much of a golfing language. But I think this site needs more Prolog.

```
s(N,N,N,79).
s(R,R,_,92).
s(R,C,N,47):-R+C=:=2*N.
s(N,_,N,45).
s(_,N,N,124).
s(_,_,_,32).
c(_,C,N):-C>2*N,nl.
c(R,C,N):-s(R,C,N,S),put(S),X is C+1,c(R,X,N).
r(R,N):-R>2*N.
r(R,N):-c(R,0,N),X is R+1,r(X,N).
g(N):-r(0,N).
```

Tested with `swipl` on Linux. Invoke like so: `swipl -s asciiSun.prolog`; then query for your desired size of sun:

```
?- g(3).
\  |  /
 \ | /
  \|/
---O---
  /|\
 / | \
/  |  \
true .
```

Ungolfed:

```
 % Args to sym/4 are row, column, N and the character code to be output at that location.
sym(N,N,N,79).
sym(R,R,_,'\\').
sym(R,C,N,'/') :- R+C =:= 2*N.
sym(N,_,N,'-').
sym(_,N,N,'|').
sym(_,_,_,' ').

 % Args to putCols/3 are row, column, and N.
 % Recursively outputs the characters in row from col onward.
putCols(_,C,N) :- C > 2*N, nl.
putCols(R,C,N) :- sym(R,C,N,S), put_code(S), NextC is C+1, putCols(R,NextC,N).

 % Args to putRows/2 are row and N.
 % Recursively outputs the grid from row downward.
putRows(R,N) :- R > 2*N.
putRows(R,N) :- putCols(R,0,N), NextR is R+1, putRows(NextR,N).

putGrid(N) :- putRows(0,N).
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>142</s> <s>140</s> <s>134</s> 117 bytes

```
n=>(g=x=>x?`${t=` `[r=`repeat`](n-x--)}\\${s=` `[r](x)}|${s}/${t}
`+g(x):`-`[r](n))(n)+`O`+[...g(n)].reverse().join``
```

---

### Try It

```js
f=
n=>(g=x=>x?`${t=` `[r=`repeat`](n-x--)}\\${s=` `[r](x)}|${s}/${t}
`+g(x):`-`[r](n))(n)+`O`+[...g(n)].reverse().join``
i.addEventListener("input",_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value))
o.innerText=f(i.value=1)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, <s>108</s> <s>97</s> 93 bytes

```
filter f{try{$s=' '*--$_
"\$s|$s/"
$_|f|%{(" $_ ","-$_-")[$_-match'O']}
"/$s|$s\"}catch{'O'}}
```

Explanation:

- the recursive algorithm throws an exception on `$s=' '*--$_` when current number less then 1;
- the output is a perfect rectangle with trailing spaces.

Less golfed test script:

```
filter f{
    try{
        $s=' '*--$_
        "\$s|$s/"
        $_|f|%{(" $_ ","-$_-")[$_-match'O']}
        "/$s|$s\"
    }catch{
        'O'
    }
}

@(

,(0,"O")
,(1,"\|/",
    "-O-",
    "/|\")
,(2,"\ | /",
    " \|/ ",
    "--O--",
    " /|\ ",
    "/ | \")
,(3,"\  |  /",
    " \ | / ",
    "  \|/  ",
    "---O---",
    "  /|\  ",
    " / | \ ",
    "/  |  \")

) | % {
    $n,$expected = $_
    $result = $n|f
    "$result"-eq"$expected"
    $result
}
```

Output:

```
True
O
True
\|/
-O-
/|\
True
\ | /
 \|/ 
--O--
 /|\ 
/ | \
True
\  |  /
 \ | / 
  \|/  
---O---
  /|\  
 / | \ 
/  |  \
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki), <s>12</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ｐ*⊕θO
```

-7 bytes thanks to *@ASCII-only*, by using the builtin `:*`.

[Try it online (verbose)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@3NKckM6AoM69Ew0pLxzMvuSg1NzWvJDVFo1BT05oLIqPkr6Rp/f@/8X/dshwA) or [try it online (pure)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9ng1aj7qmntvh//@/MQA).

**Explanation:**

Print the 8-armed lines with a length of the input+1 (the +1 is because the center is included), without moving the cursor position:

```
MultiPrint(:*, Incremented(q));
Ｐ*⊕θ
```

Then print the "O" at the current location (still in the center, because we haven't moved due to the `MultiPrint`):

```
Print("O");
O
```

Comment: [5?](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@3NKckM6AoM69Ew0pLxzMvuSg1NzWvJDVFo1BT05oLIqPkr6Rp/f@/8X/dshwA)

Comment: @ASCII-only Thanks! Didn't even knew there was a `:*` builtin for this.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy - 113

```
f={n->s=2*n+1;(1..s).each{r->(1..s+1).each{c->print c==r?n+1==r?"O":"\\":c==s-r+1?"/":c==n+1?"|":c>s?"\n":" "}}}
```

I think the ternary logic could probably be cleaned up to give a shorter answer...

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 87 bytes

```
INPUT N
FOR Y=-N TO N
FOR X=-N TO N?" \/|-     O"[(X==Y)+!(X+Y)*2+!X*3+!Y*4];
NEXT?NEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>26</s> 25 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Pub golfing so, as usual, could probably be shorter.

```
Æ"\\|/"¬qXçÃÔp'OiUç-¹·ê û
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=xiJcXHwvIqxxWOfD1HAnT2lV5y25t%2bog%2bw&input=Mw)

```
Æ"\\|/"¬qXçÃÔp'OiUç-¹·ê û     :Implicit input of integer U
Æ                             :Map each X in the range [0,U)
 "\\|/"¬                      :  Split the string "\|/"
        q                     :  Join with
         Xç                   :    X spaces
           Ã                  :End map
            Ô                 :Reverse
             p                :Push
              'Oi             :  "O" prepended with
                 Uç-          :    "-" repeated U times
                    ¹         :End push
                     ·        :Join with newlines
                      ê       :Palindromise
                        û     :Centre pad each line with spaces to the length of the longest
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
╵⌐|＊⁸／＋↔ω↶ｎ┼O╋
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyNTc1JXUyMzEwJTdDJXVGRjBBJXUyMDc4JXVGRjBGJXVGRjBCJXUyMTk0JXUwM0M5JXUyMUI2JXVGRjRFJXUyNTNDTyV1MjU0Qg__,i=Mw__,v=8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 99 bytes

```
.+
$* X$&$*-
 ( *)X(-+)
$1\|/¶$2X$2¶$1/|\
+`^ ( *.)( *)
$1$2 | $2/¶$&
+` ( */)( *).+$
$&¶$1$2 | $2\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcs7DoAgEIThfk@xxYTwCCCchoIYLSxsLIwl5/IAXgxZYzXF/825Xfux9h4cwXKBgvXEmq0p2jtDSLXF50YuyGNSbJXcMosIRtgQyNwYWZgaUVr8WnAgKLn9pPaephc) Explanation:

```
.+
$* X$&$*-
```

Place the `X` and draw `n` `-`s to its right. This completes the output for `n=0`.

```
 ( *)X(-+)
$1\|/¶$2X$2¶$1/|\
```

If `n>0` then copy the `-`s to the left, and add the first level of `\|/` and `/|\` around the `X`. This completes the output for `n=1`.

```
+`^ ( *.)( *)
$1$2 | $2/¶$&
```

Extend the `\|/` upwards, removing a space of indent each time, adding it back on each side of the `|`.

```
+` ( */)( *).+$
$&¶$1$2 | $2\
```

Extend the `/|\` downwards, removing a space of indent each time, adding it back on each side of the `|`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 46 bytes

```
(\\n›↳⁰↲\|\/n›↲⁰↳Ṡ,)\O-?-,(\/n›↲⁰↳\|\\n›↳⁰↲Ṡ,)
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%28%5C%5Cn%E2%80%BA%E2%86%B3%E2%81%B0%E2%86%B2%5C%7C%5C%2Fn%E2%80%BA%E2%86%B2%E2%81%B0%E2%86%B3%E1%B9%A0%2C%29%5CO-%3F-%2C%28%5C%2Fn%E2%80%BA%E2%86%B2%E2%81%B0%E2%86%B3%5C%7C%5C%5Cn%E2%80%BA%E2%86%B3%E2%81%B0%E2%86%B2%E1%B9%A0%2C%29&inputs=3&header=&footer=)

A mess that I can't be bothered fixing, at least for now.