# Tips for golfing in Elixir

Tags: code-golf, tips

[Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/) is a relatively new functional language, which I've taken a deep interest in. I'd like to get general tips about golfing in Elixir and learn techniques that can be applied to code-golf problems that are somewhat specific to Elixir in general.

---

*Based on so many similar questions about [Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python), [Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby), [Javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript), etc. I'll also try to post tips as I learn more about the language.*

Comment: What does Elixir running on the Erlang VM have to do with the Erlang language?

Answer (score 2):

#### Don't use the Pipe operator or parenthesis for calling methods

```
# With Pipe
arg |> M.a |> M.b |> M.c   # 24 Bytes
arg|>M.a|>M.b|>M.c         # 18 Bytes

# With Parenthesis
M.c(M.b(M.a(arg)))         # 18 Bytes

# Only Spaces
M.c M.b M.a arg            # 15 Bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

#### String and char arguments don't need spaces

For example, `IO.puts"Hello, World!"` and `IO.puts'cat'` are valid programs.

Answer (score 2):

### Inject code into strings

Instead of concatenating something into a string, like:

```
"prefix"<>code<>"suffix"
```

You can use `#{}` to insert it into the string:

```
"prefix#{code}suffix"
```

This will save 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Avoid arrow functions where possible

...and use the `&<func>(&1,&2...)` notation. For example:

```elixir
each 0..25,fn x->IO.puts slice(concat(a,a),x,26) # 48 bytes
each 0..25,&IO.puts slice(concat(a,a),&1,26)     # 44 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Map Arguments don't need spaces either

Like [LegionMammal978's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65843/19584), you can leave out space when passing Map as an argument to a method:

```
IO.inspect%{a: 1,b: 2}
```

Comment: Can you similarly remove the spaces after the colons?

Comment: Sadly, no. But you can remove spaces after semicolons and commas.

Answer (score 1):

## `use Bitwise`

Say you want to import the module `Bitwise`, usually you would do:

```
import Bitwise
```

But there may be an alternative that works in some versions of Elixir:

```
use Bitwise
```

to save 3 bytes!

Even better if your only using a bit wise operator once, you can do:

```
Bitwise.&&&()
```

`&&&` being one of the many bitwise operators useable.

Comment: If you only need one bitwise op you can use `Bitwise.&&&()` or whatever too