# Sort an Integer List

Tags: code-golf, sorting, integer

## The Challenge

It's quite simple really, sort a list of numbers.

## Details

You must sort a list of numbers in ascending order, without using any built-in sorting functions/libraries/etc (i.e. `list.sort()` in Python).

Input/output can be done in any method you choose, as long as it is human readable.

Standard loopholes are disallowed as always.

Shortest code in bytes wins.

You must explain/list what sort method you used (Bubble, Insertion, Selection, etc.)

Input will not contain duplicates.

## Sample Input/Output

Input: `99,-2,53,4,67,55,23,43,88,-22,36,45`

Output: `-22,-2,4,23,36,43,45,53,55,67,88,99`

Note: A near direct opposite of [Sort a List of Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/428/sort-a-list-of-numbers)

Comment: I'm very surprised if this isn't a duplicate, but I don't have the time to check. Anyway, "built-in sorting functions" should be better defined. Can you use a function that indexes all values? `[7 2 4 1] -> [4 2 3 1]`. Also, can the CSV list be inside brackets? Also, the specific input format is very suitable for some languages, and bad for others. This makes input parsing a big part for some submissions, and unnecessary for others.

Comment: @StewieGriffin I've seen many sorting challenges, but none dealing with sorting just a basic integer list. There are many challenges that are easier for some languages, and much more difficult in others.

Comment: [This](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75973/a-classic-sorting-code-golf-question) is *very* similar, but has a O(Nlog(N)) restriction.

Comment: Very closely related to [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12824/194), but since some answers here (e.g. Dennis' range filtering) require the input to be integers I won't vote to close as dupe.

Comment: Relevant: https://www.youtube.com/user/AlgoRythmics/videos — An Youtube channel which teaches sorting algorithms through Hungarian dances!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

Code:

```
œß
```

Same algorithm as the [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77842/34388). Computes all permutations of the input and pops out the smallest one.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xZPDnw&input=Wzk5LC0yLDUzLDQsNjcsNTUsMjMsNDNd)

---

A more efficient method is:

```
E[ß,Ž
```

Performs **selection sort**. Uses **CP-1252** encoding.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RVvDnyzFvQ&input=OTksLTIsNTMsNCw2Nyw1NSwyMyw0Myw4OCwtMjIsMzYsNDU)

Comment: Accepting this temporarily as I don't see anyone getting less than 2.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos well, if they did, it would be a builtin, wouldn't it?

Comment: I just looked at 05AB1E/Base a minute ago, and then I looked at this. Coincidence?

Answer (score 21):

## Jelly, 3 bytes

```
Œ!Ṃ
```

This generates all permutations of the input list, then selects the lexographically smallest permutation. *Very* efficient.

Credits to @Adnan who had the same idea independently.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZIh4bmC&input=&args=OTksLTIsNTMsNCw2Nyw1NSwyMyw0Mw)

---

## Jelly, 4 bytes

```
ṂrṀf
```

This builds the range from the minimum of the list to the maximum of the list, then discards the range elements not present in the original list. This is technically a **bucket sort**, with very small buckets. I'm not aware of a name for this specific variant.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmCcuG5gGY&input=&args=OTksLTIsNTMsNCw2Nyw1NSwyMyw0Myw4OCwtMjIsMzYsNDU)

#### How it works

```
ṂrṀf  Main link. Argument: A (list/comma-separated string)

Ṃ     Compute the minimum of A.
  Ṁ   Compute the maximum of A.
 r    Yield the inclusive range from the minimum to the maximum.
   f  Filter the range by presence in A.
```

Comment: O(*very*). Uses much sort.

Comment: So O. Very uses. Much sort. Amaze! (Sorry, what?)

Comment: I'm not great at complexity of algorithms, would this be O(n!)?

Comment: @FlipTack Neither am I. Probably a bit higher, since there are **n!** arrays of length **n**.

Comment: Just selecting the smallest lexographically is O(n\*n!) since each of the n! arrays must be compared sequentially, and lexographical comparison is O(n).  Generation can be done in O(n\*n!) as well if done efficiently so I would bet the algorithm is *only* O(n*n!) if well implemented

Answer (score 14):

## Python, <strike>46</strike> 45 bytes

```
lambda l:[l.pop(l.index(min(l)))for _ in 1*l]
```

Simple selection sort.

Comment: `l[:]` could be `1*l`

Answer (score 13):

## x86-16 machine code (BubbleSort int8_t), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

## x86-64/32 machine code (JumpDownSort) <s>21</s> 19 bytes

Changelog:

- Thanks to @ped7g for the `lodsb`/`cmp [si],al` idea, and putting that together with a pointer increment / reset that I'd been looking at.  Not needing `al`/`ah` lets us use nearly the same code for larger integers.
- New (but related) algorithm, many implementation changes: Bubbly SelectionSort allows a smaller x86-64 implementation for bytes or dwords; break-even on x86-16 (bytes or words).  Also avoids the bug on size=1 that my BubbleSort has.  See below.
- It turns out that my Bubbly Selection Sort with swaps every time you find a new min is already a known algorithm, JumpDown Sort.  It's mentioned in [Bubble Sort: An Archaeological Algorithmic Analysis](https://users.cs.duke.edu/%7Eola/papers/bubble.pdf) (i.e. how did Bubble Sort become popular [despite sucking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997897/why-bubble-sort-is-not-efficient) in general for speed).

---

**Sorts 8-bit signed integers in-place**.  (Unsigned is the same code size, just change the `jge` to a `jae`).  Duplicates are not a problem.  We swap using a 16-bit rotate by 8 (with a memory destination).

**[Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort) sucks for performance**, but I've read that it's one of the smallest to implement in machine code.  This seems especially true when there are special tricks for swapping adjacent elements.  This is pretty much its only advantage, but sometimes (in real life embedded systems) that's enough advantage to use it for very short lists.

**I omitted the early termination on no swaps**.  I used Wikipedia's "optimized" BubbleSort loop which avoids looking at the last `n − 1` items when running for the `n`-th time, so the outer loop counter is the upper bound for the inner loop.

NASM listing (`nasm -l /dev/stdout`), or [plain source](https://pastebin.com/0VMzdUjj)

```
 2 address  16-bit       bubblesort16_v2:
 3          machine      ;; inputs: pointer in ds:si,  size in in cx
 4          code         ;; requires: DF=0  (cld)
 5          bytes        ;; clobbers: al, cx=0
 6                       
 7 00000000 49               dec     cx          ; cx = max valid index.  (Inner loop stops 1 before cx, because it loads i and i+1).
 8                       .outer:                 ; do{
 9 00000001 51               push    cx          ;   cx = inner loop counter = i=max_unsorted_idx
10                       .inner:                 ;   do{
11 00000002 AC               lodsb               ;     al = *p++
12 00000003 3804             cmp     [si],al     ;     compare with *p (new one)
13 00000005 7D04             jge     .noswap
14 00000007 C144FF08         rol     word [si-1], 8    ; swap
15                       .noswap:
16 0000000B E2F5             loop    .inner      ;   } while(i < size);
17 0000000D 59               pop     cx          ;  cx = outer loop counter
18 0000000E 29CE             sub     si,cx       ;  reset pointer to start of array
19 00000010 E2EF             loop    .outer      ; } while(--size);
20 00000012 C3               ret

22 00000013  size = 0x13 = 19 bytes.
```

push/pop of `cx` around the inner loop means it runs with `cx` = outer_cx down to 0.

Note that  `rol r/m16, imm8` is not an 8086 instruction, it was added later (186 or 286), but this isn't trying to be 8086 code, just 16-bit x86.  If SSE4.1 `phminposuw` would help, I'd use it.

A 32-bit version of this (still operating on 8-bit integers but with 32-bit pointers / counters) is 20 bytes (operand-size prefix on `rol word [esi-1], 8`)

Bug: size=1 is treated as size=65536, because nothing stops us from entering the outer do/while with cx=0.  (You'd normally use `jcxz` for that.)  But fortunately the 19-byte JumpDown Sort is 19 bytes and doesn't have that problem.

---

**Original x86-16 20 byte version** (without Ped7g's idea).  Omitted to save space, see the [edit history](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/149038/5) for it with a description.

---

**Performance**

Partially-overlapping store/reload (in memory-destination rotate) causes
a store-forwarding stall on modern x86 CPUs (except in-order Atom).  When a high value is bubbling upwards, this extra latency is part of a loop-carried dependency chain.  Store/reload sucks in the first place (like 5 cycle store-forwarding latency on Haswell), but a forwarding stall brings it up to more like 13 cycles.  Out-of-order execution will have trouble hiding this.

See also: [Stack Overflow: bubble sort for sorting string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318043/assembly-bubble-sort-for-sorting-string/26324630#26324630) for a version of this with a similar implementation, but with an early-out when no swaps are needed.  It uses `xchg al, ah` / `mov [si], ax` for swapping, which is 1 byte longer and causes a partial-register stall on some CPUs.  (But it may still be better than memory-dst rotate, which needs to load the value again).  My comment there has some suggestions...

---

## x86-64 / x86-32 JumpDown Sort, 19 bytes (sorts int32_t)

Callable from C using the x86-64 System V calling convention as
`int bubblyselectionsort_int32(int dummy, int *array, int dummy, unsigned long size);`  (return value = max(array[])).

This is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort, but **instead of remembering the position of the min element, swap the current candidate into the array**.  Once you've found the min(unsorted_region), store it to the end of the sorted region, like normal Selection Sort.  This grows the sorted region by one.  (In the code, `rsi` points to one past the end of the sorted region; `lodsd` advances it and `mov [rsi-4], eax` stores the min back into it.)

The name Jump Down Sort is used in [Bubble Sort: An Archaeological Algorithmic Analysis](https://users.cs.duke.edu/%7Eola/papers/bubble.pdf).  I guess my sort is really a Jump Up sort, because high elements jump upwards, leaving the bottom sorted, not the end.

This exchange design leads to the unsorted part of the array ending up in mostly reverse-sorted order, leading to lots of swaps later on.  (Because you start with a large candidate, and keep seeing lower and lower candidates, so you keep swapping.)  I called it "bubbly" even though it moves elements the other direction.  The way it moves elements is also a little bit like a backwards insertion-sort.  To watch it in action, use GDB's `display (int[12])buf`, set a breakpoint on the inner `loop` instruction, and use `c` (continue).  Press return to repeat.  (The "display" command gets GDB to print the whole array state every time we hit the breakpoint).

`xchg` with mem has an implicit `lock` prefix which makes this extra slow. Probably about an order of magnitude slower than an efficient load/store swap; `xchg m,r` is one per 23c throughput on Skylake, but load / store / mov with a tmp reg for an efficient swap(reg, mem) can shift one element per clock.  It might be a worse ratio on an AMD CPU where the `loop` instruction is fast and wouldn't bottleneck the inner loop as much, but branch misses will still be a big bottleneck because swaps are common (and become more common as the unsorted region gets smaller).

```
 2 Address               ;; hybrib Bubble Selection sort
 3        machine         bubblyselectionsort_int32:   ;; working, 19 bytes.  Same size for int32 or int8
 4        code               ;; input: pointer in rsi, count in rcx
 5        bytes              ;; returns: eax = max
 6                       
 7                           ;dec  ecx           ; we avoid this by doing edi=esi *before* lodsb, so we do redundant compares
 8                                               ; This lets us (re)enter the inner loop even for 1 element remaining.
 9                       .outer:
10                           ; rsi pointing at the element that will receive min([rsi]..[rsi+rcx])
11 00000000 56               push   rsi
12 00000001 5F               pop    rdi
13                           ;mov    edi, esi     ; rdi = min-search pointer
14 00000002 AD               lodsd
16 00000003 51               push   rcx          ; rcx = inner counter
17                       .inner:                   ; do {
18                           ; rdi points at next element to check
19                           ; eax = candidate min
20 00000004 AF               scasd                 ; cmp eax, [rdi++]
21 00000005 7E03             jle  .notmin
22 00000007 8747FC           xchg   [rdi-4], eax   ; exchange with new min.
23                         .notmin:
24 0000000A E2F8             loop  .inner          ; } while(--inner);
26                           ; swap min-position with sorted position
27                           ; eax = min.  If it's not [rsi-4], then [rsi-4] was exchanged into the array somewhere
28 0000000C 8946FC           mov    [rsi-4], eax
29 0000000F 59               pop   rcx           ; rcx = outer loop counter = unsorted elements left
30 00000010 E2EE             loop  .outer        ; } while(--unsorted);
32 00000012 C3               ret

34 00000013 13           .size: db $ - bubblyselectionsort_int32
           0x13 = 19 bytes long
```

Same code size for `int8_t`: use `lodsb` / `scasb`, `AL`, and change the `[rsi/rdi-4]` to `-1`.  The same machine-code works in 32-bit mode for 8/32-bit elements.  16-bit mode for 8/16-bit elements needs to be re-built with the offsets changed (and 16-bit addressing modes use a different encoding).  But still 19 bytes for all.

It avoids the initial `dec ecx` by comparing with the element it just loaded before moving on.  On the last iteration of the outer loop, it loads the last element, checks if it's less than itself, then is done.  This allows it to work with size=1, where my BubbleSort fails (treats it as size = 65536).

I tested this version (in GDB) using the this caller:  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVVLb@M2EL7rV8yhwNobSk382thGDs1hgZyzt0UQUOLYYiORrkjFcov@9nQ4lGxlmxhIJM7rm/lmOJLOYZ1Xp9RIV7@9be8ffjzCapEA/bZbKE95o3O4b/O8QnjECguvrQFnG5/kQXpygzDInrXx89kmOh9t86LNXsDNGvKTR5cBPMoawem/EXa2AbaG@HI7YGpzaP0GDpaEGFTQOC2gsK3xfCq6wbRB3zbGbQBlB3dQyy6JKoUFABYdXH6UD4J8tVqBL7WjjEARxB5Q6Tt0Gr7mSDnhV6iscrmgGoOHsoSiWqMkoRe2PsgGXQKf/LbwI8Su0DtoHUwanCJX4Uuk3A29VdYeAF/RMAM3QPTVZEMotdSGEsqSzLbks4mlhOojGSFZ6TnU4ORLEhx1VZF7gfoVodZm8pNcnrIsPK6IracpRzq0rqQHCeOR0ghHFY/b2r6GJ7EhINDRgysdiNUmdSibohzawj6BKJW8Cz6mfMvHu75u7h85ZnzcfEAdUf1PcoFlJBcqNtj5S8kWihKLl94ydr6QRmklPdfPGldIpz4AKepD8BHwkzCurp7Y@E8absiM9YN3V5R7egSbdPEkGIXRSCHNHolzX1Jex4CXJWfnTc9L4DYWekH@F46lrnCSpqyYbvtZBXeUB6b4YJ3m68XRw31CBYPwXb0BFeBhB9p/cUDYEJrNqdJ4mOEER@nOOatwyyyPj2waeSKAGo8lNsih@/6f4xDQaE6aX@5S7CzPaSy3by8JW9Nn3ncsXIedHxMT3T4gZnAduKH7nSRZWBcbUDn8Bil8unSSN9cvp4wGQSbbvN3xlJHjjHaQgKWAdE5v397pWML6awEzhpWV3hu4WfFBKUhJefkLKdNsOkJ6lVWLkX/aCx7sjvLbxU6dIRSs1yKdieVcLIJArL6J5VLM6DgXt7ekmon5SiyWychlbE9mwYZ82Cz4U8RZcE7QqODFkPTCmxX/amESFUzYbgq/w@JczOJ6vQp1XM8WVHP3/fv4f@zI@/JoaKhxL7yv6L2WL7TC2wbjejRfPKmlCsPABNAgKJckybkdnq7v/3ndVzaXFTw7T8wl8bG5TCKGnT@QGSVFJ841cp7jGkd2eccbLI5QIWk5fjo0cZbjVyR8Pmh81@vk11iyG0YVO@0nZDfNRjZhm9zwmWIC0Xh7Pb4q81maaw9/3D@AO7lnDjEV/HV04Xu2WrC@sIoupiNSqypL3v4D).  You can run this it on TIO, but of course no debugger or printing.  Still, the `_start` that calls it exits with exit-status = largest element = 99, so you can see it works.

Comment: There might be room to improve on the inner-loop loop condition, it seems to be using a lot of bytes.  Maybe push/pop `cx` and use `loop` for both?  Maybe loop the other way, from back to front of the array so we count an index down to zero?  (And increment `bx` because the sorted portion is at the end you loop towards).

Comment: Got it down to 19B, but with lot of changes, also input regs (some changes probably not needed, but as I was toying around, they remained there from earlier experiments)... it's still based on your work, so reluctant to post it as answer, you can check it on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/0VMzdUjj

Comment: @Ped7g: Nice!  I'd considered `sub si, cx` as part of the outer loop using a pointer instead of indexing, but I hadn't thought of `lodsb` / `cmp [si], al`.  I'd been considering `lodsw` / `dec si`, or `lodsb` /`xchg al,ah`to still set up for `cmp ah,al`

Comment: @Ped7g: oh, your version requires `cld`, or I guess we could make that part of the calling convention.  AFAIK, having `DF` cleared is not a standard part of 16-bit calling conventions, only 32/64.  Or is it just that you can't assume it in a bootloader?  But with a custom register calling convention, this is as much of a code fragment as a function, so sure, why not require DF=0.  (And if we want, ES=DS so we could `scasb` instead of `lodsb` if that's more convenient.)

Comment: I can't recall any 16b calling convention (I never used them, my asm was always custom, using custom set of registers per function, not even having uniform convention), so I don't know about DF either. (as I don't know rules of this site, I may have broken it by using completely custom scheme and DF=0 requirement. But overall; is even x86-16b calling convention a thing? Didn't have pretty much every language compiler its own? I'm pretty sure BorlandC vs WatcomC was not compatible by default, Pascal was different too, DOS `int 21h` completely custom, etc... it's stone age and anarchy ;) :) )

Comment: @Ped7g: I have no idea about 16-bit conventions, all I know is that you couldn't always assume DF was cleared.  But I think that's mostly in a bootloader context.  I've never run anything I've written on real DOS.  I was on Atari Mega 4 STe (68000/68020), then Linux (on a Pentium MMX), so I managed to avoid 16-bit x86 entirely until SO questions rammed it down my throat.

Comment: @Ped7g: In pure assembly language, you can make up whatever calling convention you want.  It's only interfacing with compilers or other libraries that you need to stick to any kind of standard.  Thus, an asm function can do whatever you like, IMO as long as it's something you might reasonably expect your caller to do.  (e.g. not copy an arg to multiple registers, but any arbitrary register is fine.)

Comment: @Ped7g: Anyway, I updated this answer.  It's pretty common for people to suggest improvements, even major changes, and people edit them into their answers.  That works better for the site than having multiple answers in the same language that use basically the same strategy.  Thanks again.

Comment: I went through Z80 (ZX Spectrum) to x86-16, because we had few 286 PC AT computers around at universities in city (where I could "break in" through some adults from family)... did whole "sprite editor" in 320x200 in pure x86-16 at high school, then a friend somewhere downloaded Watcom C and we learned to use DOS4GW for 32b protected mode under DOS ... but our first PC demo was in 16b ... would be lot of pain today, but as I was coming from ZX, it was nice change to have several(!) 64kiB memory banks available, compared to ~39kiB of ZX 48k and 128kiB banking of 128k. 450+kiB RAM = astonishing!

Comment: @Ped7g: x86-64 version for 32-bit integers only costs 2 extra bytes.  Your `lodsb`/`cmp` idea was key.  IDK if it's reasonable for the function to expect the caller to pass the max idx in the first place, instead of the size.  I don't think anyone would complain, but I'd rather golf this function than "cheat" that way.

Comment: @Ped7g: x86-64 version is down to 19 bytes, using a new algo that isn't quite SelectionSort.  (And an `xchg` with mem to thoroughly destroy performance :P).  It avoids the initial `dec ecx` by comparing with the element it just loaded before moving on.

Comment: Nice tutorial on machine code, and sort algorithms!  And I thought I was hot stuff writing an assembler routine for the Commodore 64 6502 chip!

Comment: @MarkStewart: Thanks.  Each machine has code-golf (and performance) tricks that are unique to them, and 6502 especially has some interesting(?) constraints/features like few registers but zero-page memory-indirect addressing that are different from modern CPUs.  So I'm sure there's plenty of fun to be had with 6502 asm / machine code, especially if one is interested in retrocomputing or just code-golf on different historical ISAs.

Answer (score 10):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>12</s> 7 bytes

```
p.'(s>)
```

This uses permutation sort, which is obviously terrible, but hey it's shorter than Pyth!

#### Explanation

```
p.       Unifies the output with a permutation of the input
  '(  )  True if what's inside the parentheses cannot be proven, else backtrack and
         try with another permutation of the input.
    s    Take an ordered subset from the output
     >   True if the first element is bigger than the second (hence not sorted)
         We don't need to check that the subset is 2 elements long because > will be false
         for inputs that are not 2 elements long anyway
```

Answer (score 10):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 205 bytes

```sql
WITH s AS(SELECT COLUMN_VALUE||''e FROM XMLTABLE(('"'||REPLACE(:1,',','","')||'"'))),v(p,f)AS(SELECT e,e FROM s UNION ALL SELECT p||','||e,e FROM v,s WHERE e+0>f)SELECT p FROM v WHERE LENGTH(p)=LENGTH(:1);
```

Un-golfed

```sql
WITH 
s AS  -- Split the string using ',' as separator
(     -- ||'' cast the xml type to varchar
  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE||''e FROM XMLTABLE(('"'||REPLACE(:1,',','","')||'"'))
),  
v(p,f) AS  -- Recursive view : p = sorted string, f last number added
(
  SELECT e,e FROM s -- use each number as seed
  UNION ALL         -- only add a number if it is > the last added
  SELECT p||','||e,e FROM v,s WHERE e+0>f  -- +0 is needed to compare int and not strings
)  
-- The valid string has the same length as the input
SELECT p FROM v WHERE LENGTH(p)=LENGTH(:1)
```

As for what sort method it is, I have no idea, `ORDER BY` made sure I forgot them.

Comment: I barely know SQL, but from your comments I think you're selecting the min or max from the remaining unsorted elements, and appending that to the end of a sorted list.  That makes this a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort.

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, 38 bytes

```haskell
h%t|(a,b)<-span(<h)t=a++h:b
foldr(%)[]
```

The binary function `%` insert a new element `h` into a sorted list `t` by partitioning `t` into a prefix `a` of elements `<h` and a suffix `b` of elements `>h`, and sticks in `h` between them.

The operation `foldr(%)[]` then builds up a sorted list from empty by repeatedly inserting elements from the input list.

This is one byte shorter than the direct recursive implementation

```haskell
f(h:t)|(a,b)<-span(<h)$f t=a++h:b
f x=x
```

Another strategy for 41 bytes:

```haskell
f[]=[]
f l|x<-minimum l=x:f(filter(/=x)l)
```

Comment: So this is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort, with `%` as the insertion inner loop and `foldr` to apply it as the outer loop.

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), 51 bytes

```
a=>a.map(_=>m=Math.min(...a.filter(e=>e>m)),m=-1/0)
```

Each loop finds the smallest number that hasn't been found so far.

Comment: Calling this on `[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]` produces `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity]`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum "Input will not contain duplicates."

Comment: I have the exact same bytecount with a different approach

Comment: Actually, 1 byte less

Comment: This algorithm is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, <s>42</s> <s>41</s> 38 bytes

```
f u=filter(`elem`u)[(minBound::Int)..]
```

Loops through all integers (signed 64bit, on my machine) and keeps those that are in `u`. Of course it doesn't finish in reasonable time.

The previous version looped through `[minimum u..maximum u]` which has the same worst case running time.

Edit: @xnor saved a byte. Thanks!

Comment: `filter` is one shorter: ``f u=filter(`elem`u)[minimum u..maximum u]``

Comment: How brute force! Does `[minimum u..]` not work for type reasons?

Comment: @xnor: I think so. When calling, let's say `f [1,3,0]`, the elements default to type `Integer` which is unbound, so the `..` never ends. If you have to call it like `f ([1, 3, 0]::[Int])` then I guess, the type annotation has to be included in the byte count.

Comment: How does it detect elements that occur more than once?

Comment: @feersum: it doesn't, but the challenge says: "Input will not contain duplicates".

Answer (score 8):

### Python 2, 34 bytes

```python
def f(s):m=min(s);print m;f(s-{m})
```

Takes input as a set, printing its elements in increasing order, terminating with error.

A clean termination can be done in 41 bytes:

```python
def f(s):
 if s:m=min(s);print m;f(s-{m})
```

or

```python
l=input()
while l:m=min(l);print m;l-={m}
```

The input can be take as a list for 39 bytes, or 38 bytes in Python 3.5:

```python
def f(l):m=min(l);print m;f(set(l)-{m})
def f(l):m=min(l);print(m);f({*l}-{m})
```

Comment: This is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort, using `m=min(s)` / `s - (m)` as the inner loop to find and remove the min from the unsorted elements, and recursion as the outer.

Answer (score 7):

## C, 72 bytes

```
i,j;a(int*l,int n){for(i=0;i=i?:--n;j>l[n]?l[i]=l[n],l[n]=j:0)j=l[--i];}
```

Bubblesort. The first argument is a pointer to the array, the second argument is the length of the array. Works with gcc.

Comment: This really needs an ungolfed version to be readable; it's really hard to keep track of where the ternary operators start / end.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, <s>91</s> <s>62</s> 47 bytes

```python
def f(z):
 while z:m=min(z);z.remove(m);yield m
```

Thanks to [wnnmaw](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30170/wnnmaw) and [Seeq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20356/seeq) for golfing help.

The argument `z` should be a list. This is a variant of selection sort.

I'm not sure how `min` stacks up against `built-in sorting functions`, since I'm not sure how Python implements `min`. Hopefully, this solution is still okay. Any golfing suggestions in the comments or in [PPCG chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) are welcome.

Comment: Make sure to state what type of sort you are using.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos I've honestly forgotten what algorithm this is. Might be selection sort?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not just directly take a list? The question allows for open input format

Comment: @wnnmaw Dang it, I wrote one up but forgot to post it. Thanks for the reminder :D

Comment: Hmm, maybe `def f(z):\nwhile z:m=min(z);z.remove(m);yield m`

Comment: This is definitely https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort.  It scans the entire remaining list of elements for the min element (using `m=min(z);`), and returns it as the next generated value with `yield`.  `min()` implements the inner loop of Selection Sort, `while z:` implements the outer loop.  `.remove` may be a lot less efficient than swapping the new min into place (`remove` has to find it again), but it's still Selection in a loop.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
Y@t!d0>AY)
```

Extremely inefficient examination of all permutations of the input.

[**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WUB0IWQwPkFZKQ&input=Wzk5LC0yLDUzLDRd)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input array
Y@      % Compute all permutations (each permutation as a row)
t       % Duplicate this matrix
!d      % Transpose and take the differences between the values
0>A     % Find the rows where all differences are > 0
Y)      % Return only the row where this is true
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 120 Bytes

```
def f(a):import time,threading;[threading.Thread(None,lambda b=b,c=min(a):print(time.sleep(b-c)or b)).start()for b in a]
```

This probably won't be the shortest answer but I feel like this algorithm belongs here. call with a list of integers, they'll be printed in a sorted manner to stdout. I wouldn't try it with too large numbers though.

Comment: Nice first post! And nice username. :P

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 40 bytes

Selection sort. Anonymous function; takes the list as argument.

```
->a{r=[];r<<a.delete(a.min)while[]!=a;r}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Awk, 66 bytes

```
{b=$0;a[b]}m<b{m=b}n>b{n=b}END{for(i=n;i<=m;i++)if(i in a)print i}
```

Arrays in awk are like dictionaries, not like C arrays. The indexes can be non-contiguous, and they grow (and are created) as needed. So, we create an array `a` for the input, with each line being a key. And we save the min and max values. Then we loop from min to max, and print all keys which exist in `a`. `b` is just to avoid repeated usage of `$0`.

Comment: This is a couple chars shorter...

`!a[b=$0]&&m<b{m=b}n>b{n=b}END{for(;n<=m;n++)if(n in a)print n}`

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth - <s>15</s> <s>13</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

*Two bytes saved thanks to @Jakube.*

Bogosort.

```
f!s>VTtT.p
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%21s%3EVTtT.p&input=4%2C1%2C3&debug=0).

I don't need the `h` cuz we are guaranteed no duplicates.

Comment: @Jakube I feel stupid, thanks.

Comment: @Suever as I said in my answer, we are guaranteed no duplicates as per OP.

Comment: Sorry about that! Missed that point.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
`t4#X<2#)tn
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YHQ0I1g8MiMpdG4&input=Wy0zIC03IC02IC01IC02IDUgNiA0IDMgMCBd)

This sorts by the following procedure, which is *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>):

1. Take the minimum of the array.
2. Remove that value from the array, and store it for subsequent display.
3. Apply the same procedure with the rest of the array, until it becomes empty.
4. Display all numbers in the order in which they were obtained.

MATL is stack-based. The array with remaining values is kept at the top of the stack. The removed values are below, in order. At the end of the program all those values are displayed. The array at the top would also be displayed, but since it's empty it's not shown.

```
`        % Do...while loop
  t      %   Duplicate. Implicitly take input in the first iteration
  4#X<   %   Compute index of mininum of the array
  2#)    %   Push the minimum, and then the array with remaining entries
  tn     %   Duplicate and push number of elements, to be used as loop condition
         % Implicitly end do...while loop
         % Implicitly display stack contents
```

Answer (score 4):

### Java 8, <s>112</s> 92 bytes

Here is another selection sort. The input is a `List t` of integers and the sorted output is printed to standard out.

```java
t->{for(;0<t.size();System.out.println(t.remove(t.indexOf(java.util.Collections.min(t)))));}
```

**Update**

- **-20** [16-08-21] Used a lambda

Comment: Hi Nonlinear, and welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! It appears your code assumes a variable `t` to exist, which makes it a snippet; we require submissions to be [full programs or functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/20469) which utilize our [default I/O formats](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/20469). We also require imports to factor into the byte count. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks for the resources! I modified my answer to be a function and to include the import.

Answer (score 4):

## MIPS, 68 bytes

I wrote a simple unoptimized bubble sort implementation a while ago. Byte count begins at `loop` and ends at `li $v0, 10`, assuming that the list address and list length are already in memory.

```
 Address    Code        Basic                     Source

0x00400000  0x3c011001  lui $1,4097           5    main:   la      $s0, list       # List address
0x00400004  0x34300000  ori $16,$1,0               
0x00400008  0x2411000a  addiu $17,$0,10       6            li      $s1, 10         # List length
0x0040000c  0x24080000  addiu $8,$0,0         8    loop:   li      $t0, 0          # swapped
0x00400010  0x24090001  addiu $9,$0,1         9            li      $t1, 1          # for loop "i"
0x00400014  0x1131000b  beq $9,$17,11         11   for:    beq     $t1, $s1, fend  # break if i==length
0x00400018  0x00095080  sll $10,$9,2          13           sll     $t2, $t1, 2     # Temp index, multiply by 4
0x0040001c  0x01505020  add $10,$10,$16       14           add     $t2, $t2, $s0   # Combined address
0x00400020  0x8d4b0000  lw $11,0($10)         15           lw      $t3, 0($t2)     # list[i]
0x00400024  0x8d4cfffc  lw $12,-4($10)        16           lw      $t4, -4($t2)    # list[i-1]
0x00400028  0x21290001  addi $9,$9,1          18           addi    $t1, $t1, 1     # i++
0x0040002c  0x016c082a  slt $1,$11,$12        20           ble     $t4, $t3, for   # if list[i-1] > list[i]
0x00400030  0x1020fff8  beq $1,$0,-8               
0x00400034  0xad4bfffc  sw $11,-4($10)        21           sw      $t3, -4($t2)    # swap and store
0x00400038  0xad4c0000  sw $12,0($10)         22           sw      $t4, 0($t2)     
0x0040003c  0x24080001  addiu $8,$0,1         23           li      $t0, 1          # swapped=true
0x00400040  0x08100005  j 0x00400014          24           j       for
0x00400044  0x20010001  addi $1,$0,1          26   fend:   subi    $s1, $s1, 1     # length--
0x00400048  0x02218822  sub $17,$17,$1             
0x0040004c  0x1500ffef  bne $8,$0,-17         27           bnez    $t0, loop       # Repeat if swapped==true
0x00400050  0x2402000a  addiu $2,$0,10        29           li      $v0, 10        
0x00400054  0x0000000c  syscall               30           syscall
```

Now I wait to be blown out of the water with x86...

Comment: You can leave out the `swapped=true` early-out check and count down based on the array size.  See [my 20 byte x86-16 version that sorts 8-bit integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77836/sort-an-integer-list/149038#149038).  I might make a normal 32 or 64-bit x86 version that sorts 32-bit integers at some point, but 8-bit integers in 16-bit mode is kind of a sweet spot  for x86.

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
x->colon(extrema(x)...)∩x
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=ZiA9IHgtPmNvbG9uKGV4dHJlbWEoeCkuLi4p4oipeAoKcHJpbnQoZihbOTksLTIsNTMsNCw2Nyw1NSwyMyw0Myw4OCwtMjIsMzYsNDVdKSk&input=)

Comment: Does this build a range from min to max, and intersect with the original list?  That would be a flavour of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort, like a couple other answers: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117648/30206.  (The question does specifically require answers to say what kind of sort it is.)

Answer (score 3):

### Seriously, 6 bytes

```
,;l@╨m
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LDtsQOKVqG0&input=OTksLTIsNTMsNA)

This does the same thing as many other answers: generate all permutations, select minimum. I kinda forgot that this would work while I was working on the below solution.

Explanation:

```
,;l@╨m
,;l@    push len(input), input
    ╨m  minimum permutation
```

---

### Seriously, 25 bytes (non-competing)

This would be competitive if it wasn't for a bug in the shuffle command that I just fixed.

```
,1WX╚;;pX@dXZ`i@-0<`MπYWX
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LDFXWOKVmjs7cFhAZFhaYGlALTA8YE3PgFlXWA&input=OTksLTIsNTMsNCw2Nyw1NSwyMyw0Myw4OCwtMjIsMzYsNDU)
This implements the best sorting algorithm ever: [Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort)!

Explanation:

```
,1WX╚;;pX@dXZ`i@-0<`MπYWX
,                          get input
 1W                    WX  do-while:
   X                         discard
    ╚                        shuffle
     ;;                      dupe twice
       pX@dX                 remove first element of first dupe and last element of second dupe
            Z                zip
             `i@-0<`MπY      test if all differences are positive (if any are not, the list is not sorted), negate (1 if not sorted else 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, <s>17</s> 16 bytes

Saved one byte creating null array thanks to @LuisMendo

```
vTbtX<-QI$(f8M+q
```

Bucket sort. Don't try it with a range greater than 2<sup>31</sup>-1.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dlRidFg8LVFJJChmOE0rcQ&input=Wzk5LC0yLDUzLDQsNjcsNTUsMjMsNDMsODgsLTIyLDM2LDQ1XQ)

**Explanation**

```
v                  % push an empty array
 T                 % push 1
  b                % bubble the input array up to the top of the stack
   t               % duplicate it
    X<             % find the minimum
      -            % subtract min from input array
       Q           % and increment to adjust for 1-based indexing
        I$(        % resulting array used as indices of empty array 
                   % (the [] way up at the top) that are assigned 1 (from T)
           f       % find the nonzero indices
            8M     % magically retrieve the 4th previous function input :/
                     (aka, the min input array value)
              +    % add it to the indices
               q   % and decrement
```

---

TIL:

- You can initialize an empty array in MATL using `[]` and grow it, just like in MATLAB
- How to use `(` for assignment indexing
- How to use the `M` automatic clipboard

---

New day, new TIL:

- `vertcat` magically creates an empty array when there's nothing on the stack to concatenate

Comment: Add to your TIL: an _initial_ `[]` can be replaced by `v`. This is because the default number of inputs of `v` is the number of elements in the stack

Comment: @LuisMendo Sooo... if there is one array on the stack... ? Investigating.

Comment: Then it does nothing. Think of it as `vertcat(STACK{:})`

Answer (score 3):

## R, 68 Bytes

Takes input `i` and outputs `o` which is the sorted list.

```
o<-i
for(j in 1:length(i)){
x<-(i-min(i))==0
o[j]<-i[x]
i<-i[!x]
}
o
```

Explanation:

```
o<-i                      # Defines output as o
 for(j in 1:length(i)){   # Initializes loop for length of input
  x<-(i-min(i))==0        # Generates logical vector by finding the value 0 
                          # of input less the minimum of input. 
   o[j]<-i[x]             # Puts the smallest value at position j
    i<-i[!x]              # Removes the smallest value from input
      }                   # Ends loop
       o                  # Returns sorted list
```

Avoiding the permutations means it can sort large lists relatively quickly. The "trick" is that subtracting the smallest value from the input leaves a single 0 that determine both the smallest value and the position of the smallest value.

Answer (score 3):

### Clojure, <s>73</s> 35 bytes

[Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) :)

```
#(if(apply < %)%(recur(shuffle %)))
```

Earlier version:

```
#(reduce(fn[r i](let[[a b](split-with(partial > i)r)](concat a[i]b)))[]%)
```

Reduces to a sorted list `r` by splitting it into "smaller than i" and "larger than i" parts. I guess this is the [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Comment: Nice! I did not know you could `recur` on an anonymous function. Also didn't know about `shuffle`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda l:[i for i in range(min(l),max(l)+1)if i in l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclBCoMwEEbhvaf4lwkdwTSKIHgSdZHSpg4kowQX9vRR6@rB@9bfNi9is@/HHFx8vR1CNzD8ksBgQXLy/ajIooKm6PYzD6PZ3xqmvCaWTXk1NISaYAlPgpm0Lv6Ci1pCRSivmw8)

Comment: This is essentially a bucket sort, right? So it fails if the input doesn't fall in the range of the hash table size? Can that happen?

Comment: @Jakob I don't think so? To me it's just a range between min and max values, filtered with the input list

Comment: @ASCII-only: agreed. Filtering the range between min and max looks like an implementation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort to me, because it's sort of like making a histogram.  (Same as [@Mendeleev's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117648/30206))

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 47 bytes

implements bogosort.

```r
function(l){while(is.unsorted(l))l=sample(l);l}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchLCoAgEADQq8zSgSHoX4SHCVMSJg0/tIjObr7lC8XIYrJTyXonGN/ntKyFjU120Yekj5rIMu7XXZ9x468YoURPHbU00Ag0AcFMsBCsiOUH)

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, 95

Modified bubble sort.  I suspect there are much better ways to do this, even without the retina sort builtin.

```
-\d+
$*n
\d+
$*11
+`(1+) (n+)
$2 $1
+`\b(n+) (\1n+)|(1+)(1+) \3\b
$2$3 $1$3$4
1(1*)
$.1
n+
-$.&
```

- Stage 1 - convert -ve integers to unary with `n` as the digit; drop the `-` signs.
- Stage 2 - convert +ve and zero integers to unary with `1` as the digit; add `1` to each one, so that zero is represented by `1`.
- Stage 3 - Move all -ves to the front.
- Stage 4 - Sort: move all -ves with the largest magnitude (i.e. smallest numerical) ahead of higher -ves.  Move smaller +ves ahead of larger +ves.
- Stage 5 - Remove 1 from, and convert +ve unaries back to decimal.
- Stage 6 - convert -ve unaries back to decimal, including sign.

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LVxkKwokKm4KXGQrCiQqMTEKK2AoMSspIChuKykKJDIgJDEKK2BcYihuKykgKFwxbispfCgxKykoMSspIFwzXGIKJDIkMyAkMSQzJDQKMSgxKikKJC4xCm4rCi0kLiY&input=OTkgLTIgNTMgNCA2NyAwIDU1IDIzIDQzIDg4IC0yMiAzNiA0NQ)

Comment: [Just one byte shorter!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XgogClxkKwokKjExCitgICgxKykgKC0xKykKICQyICQxCitgICgoLTErKSBcMigxKyl8KDErKSgxKykgXDQpIAogJDIkMyQ0ICQyJDQkNSAKMSgxKikKJC4xCl4gCg&input=OTkgLTIgNTMgNCA2NyAwIDU1IDIzIDQzIDg4IC0yMiAzNiA0NQ)

Comment: @LeakyNun That doesn't sort the last element in the list.

Comment: @mbomb007 right, never mind.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 22 bytes

A *quick* permutation sort. Runs in O(n!) space and time.

```
->a{a.permutation.min}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>26</s> 24 bytes

Selection sort, similar to Value Ink's answer, but using a different approach for greater golfiness.

According to the specification: "Input/output can be done in any method you choose, as long as it is human readable". I think this fits the description, output is an array of arrays with a single element.

```
->l{l.map{l-l-=[l.min]}}
```

example:

```
->l{l.map{l-l-=[l.min]}}[[2,4,3,1]]
=> [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, <s>106</s> 104 bytes

```
void a(int[]a){for(int b=a.length-1,d=0,c=0,e;d<b*b;c=++d%b)if(a[c]>a[c+1]){e=a[c];a[c++]=a[c];a[c]=e;}}
```

Here's a good ole bubble sort. The function parameter is modified in place so I don't have to return anything. Still trying to squeeze some bytes out of this so I can beat the java lambda that someone posted.

-1 byte thanks to [Geobits](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14215/geobits) for pointing out that normal swapping beats xor'ing

-1 byte thanks to [Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun) for pointing out that I can move all the int declarations into the for-loop

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#ZU/LasMwELznK5ZAQapkEztxmiCrf9BTjkEH2ZZTgR/BVlqK8be7KwX3UtBjdpbZnSkbPY7woW0H0/LV2wo0sZ27Kk2nuh88hkLquDHdzX1GCa/kjpd4jajy4rUQpWSseimorYm@luodH5YoOhnpS@FLpv6wkkbM8wL3R9HYEkanHX5hb4seyMUNtrvh9oFOG3j6akECdOY7VIQK5J8OpScDnM5nHqU82/MDP77xLOMpwj0/nZBO@f7ID9nshW2siQ4j1nAWp@@EzdeIwjJGwS8HuPyMzrRx/3DxHX05TGhVUKOFGoiFHFYdRJDQ0Pkv2/JtUM0bPPPyCw)

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 22 bytes

```
->a{[*a.min..a.max]&a}
```

Builds an array out of the range between the minimum and maximum elements of the input array. Returns the intersection between the two arrays.

Comment: I guess that's a kind of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort.

Comment: @PeterCordes That was kinda the point

Comment: The question asks you to describe what kind of sort it is, so I thought it was useful to link to the well-known algorithm as well as just describing what it actually does.

Comment: True. Thanks @PeterCordes

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 13 bytes

Uses **bogosort**. [Try it out here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=V39aLGspb2sgVGt9aw) Replace `⌂` with `\x7f`. Input is a comma-separated list of numbers like `5,3,2,4,1`.

```
W⌂Z,k)ok Tk}k
```

Explanation:

```
W⌂Z,k)ok Tk}k
W    )         while
 ⌂Z,            !isSorted
    k            input {
      ok          k =
        _Tk        shuffle(k)
           }   }
            k  out k
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 159

Implements [bozosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort#Related_algorithms) (randomly swap two elements until the array is sorted).

It's not very efficient...

```
from random import randint as r
def b(l):
 s,a=len(l)-1,0
 while not a:
        c,d=r(0,s),r(0,s);l[d],l[c]=l[c],l[d];e,a=l[0],1
        for f in l:a,e=a*(f>=e),f
 return l
```

Comment: you can save a couple of bytes by indenting `s,a=...`, `while not a:` and `return l` with a single space, and the contents of the while loop with a single tab because tab is considered deeper indentation than space. that will make this answer python2 only, though

Comment: @undergroundmonorail Thanks!

Comment: You can probably use `while a<1`, or if `a` is always `0` or `1`, you can use `while~-a`

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript 55 bytes

```
a=>[...a].map(b=>a.splice(a.indexOf(Math.min(...a)),1)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Firefox; for the sample input I get `[[-22], [-2], [4], [23], [36], [43], , , , , , ,]`.

Comment: @Neil yeah, missed something

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl, 49:  sleep sort

The examples so far aren't very consistent in how they take input, so this sorts command-line arguments.  On particularly slow systems, where the foreach takes more than a millisecond, it might need three extra bytes (`after ${x}0`).

```
foreach x $argv {after $x puts $x}
vwait forever
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 79 bytes

```
DEF S A
FOR Z=0TO I
FOR I=1TO LEN(A)-1SWAP A[I-(A[I-1]>A[I])],A[I]NEXT
NEXT
END
```

It's bubble sort but instead of checking to see if it's finished, it just assumes that every input is the worst case and does n^2 (actually n*(n+2)) iterations.

Comment: IDK if it saves bytes in your case, but BubbleSort leaves the last `Z` elements sorted, so you can use the outer loop counter as the inner loop bound (if the outer loop counts down), like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort describes.  (See [my well-commented x86 asm bubblesort](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149038/30206))

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 65 bytes

Insertion sort subroutine:

```perl
sub r{map{$t=0;$_[$_]<$_[$t]&&($t=$_)for 0..$#_;splice@_,$t,1}@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcnRCoIwGIbhW/mgHyna3FYpyDS8D1k/FQaC5ZjrSLz2lUcvPK/vw1ikNH8fCMv77heKjbbEHbGrt0SXZfs/Eh9eU4DOc9qxnf04PPuWBUVh1pbXRKIhZX0YPhEB24@qu2lZSXdUor6mC84wKFCiwgnSaOgf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Dodos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/dodos), 75 bytes

```
	/
/
	/ s w
w
	h
	/ t
s
	s R
R
	t
	h
h
	t I q
q
	dot t
	dot
I
	I dip
t
	dab
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYq5DcAwDANrcQptYCDIt4Jbb5DARVI5hgR4fMaqeHdgbbUZKQkJktR0YECeYIdBTAsKxKPN6pq1o0Nq83mIQYZkre@H8OsmuXPlwY0nlx8)

Only support non negative integers. Terrible runtime, especially for large numbers.

---

**Explanation**

First, define `t` to be the tail of a list. (all elements except the first)

Given a list `[x,y]` where `x<y`, function `I` computes the **i**ncremental difference (with a `0` prepended), which is used in `h` (head of a list, by getting the sum of all elements, subtract by the sum of all elements except the first)

Function `R` reverses a list of 2 elements. (concatenate the **t**ail and the **h**ead) Generally, it rotates the first element to the last.

`s` sorts a list of 2 elements. Generally, given a list, it find the least non negative `n` such that rotate the list left by `n` make the list less than itself `R`ed.

`/` sorts a list of arbitrarily many elements, by `/` the list' tail, and then `/ s` the result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 97 bytes

```hs
s=f.map pure
a@(x:y)!b@(z:w)|x>z=z:a!w|0<1=x:y!b
a!b=a++b
d(x:y:z)=x!y:d z
d p=p
f[x]=x
f x=f$d x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrRCoIwFIDh@z3FGXihOEMzi0YnfA/x4ow5klSGFs7huy@7@@H7X7S8u2EIYUFzGsmC/c4dozp2cku4qmMv12R3T49eEl/3/FHgQVwx4gopTRXT/1f6BB3fpAbPNFi0zDSuRccMODSRBhdG6idAsHM/fSCCBZpSXEUhskrk4l4dnRXlRZxvbfgB)

A stable, incremental merge sort.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
_ueg#G.p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P740NV3ZXa/g//9oS0sdXSMdU2MdEx0zcx1TUx0jINM4FgA)

- `ueg#G.p`:

  - `u` Repeatedly apply the following function to the input until the result stops changing.
  - `.p`: Generate all permutations of the current list
  - `g#G`:

    - `#`: Filter the list of permutations
    - `g`: On being greater than or equal to
    - `G`: The current list
  - `e`: Take the last permutation in the filtered list. This will only be the same as the current list if the filter only leaves behind one list, because the permutation function `.p` always puts its input first.

At this point, we have the maximum permutation of the input, which is in reverse sorted order. `_` reverses that to give the sorted list.

---

Note that Pyth does not have an opposite of `g` - there is no less than or equal to builtin.

---

I wanted to see what the intermediate lists are when sorting with this method. Putting a newline at the end of the code prints all of the intermediate lists:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P740NV3ZXa@A6///aAMdcx0THUMdMx1THSMd49h/@QUlmfl5xf91UwA)

For the input `[0,7,4,1,6,5,2,3]`, here's what the intermediate lists look like:

```
[0, 7, 4, 1, 6, 5, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 4, 7, 0]
[7, 0, 4, 1, 6, 5, 2, 3]
[7, 3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 4, 0]
[7, 4, 0, 1, 6, 5, 2, 3]
[7, 5, 3, 2, 6, 1, 0, 4]
[7, 6, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4]
[7, 6, 5, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Basically, what's happening is that at each step, the (reverse) sorted prefix stays, and then the last number larger than the front unsorted number is moved to the front of the unsorted region, and the rest of the unsorted region is reversed. It's like a low-quality selection sort with reversals thrown in for fun.

I think this runs in approximately `O(n^2 n!)` time - `n!` permutations, `n` comparisons each, and `O(n)` rounds (at most `2n`, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

## [minigolf](https://github.com/jfioasd/minigolf), 48 bytes

Implements insertion sort.

```
0,;i,:#1,;ns,s,n2,;:,n_T*+0s,,_1_,o_,n__n1+,;o__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VhZc9s2EH7Xr0Dph5ARxIr0EYcaZyZt0rtN2qan6uHAJCTBoUgWgBQrf95dgLcI0mmmT/VoxiSw@@29WCI/yE2Wns7yQ364Z9s84xKJg5iUj4Svc8IFnUz0P46u6iX3OV/vtjSVr/WOHVMRcZZLlqVX1palbJ0lK8uZnKCC1SVxHJKSx360Ygl9hGF36E8ecgrihOROJf0IYrYHABMriZQWwGwJmXEaSr6jlpl0Q5NcEb7mLJWoUhvtKRcKwl5lHEUbGr1l6Ro9f/MK7fKYSCoca1Cr6L/T6tVO5juJEiYkylYoymKaZ6CoQAR@yjegltIExAtgKBXS/5RKwoY9tlIxE@4@0LJyZalt7efuKXCqFXrHpD0HSoWvxFrW/RwvGA5OPLxIBRY49fEiwGn45vF0LjAOvRBnIbyHqTfFiywM74FpIiSJ3gLA8hqkpqC5qF/Ukw2J5QoZs9TllMS2M7X@Si3HFXkCCujnifI3QyyFn1gGM@@6UBpsSGhqMwc9Q/Og9lm04yol6Z4ksFcvA7XKHlttO@hKJ1HQcXShnUvynKaxrfxrb0luZzzGGtRxGjSaCDrGrelbBmu04q1eDll8B1vzySSmqyJMtvJ2oPMbzZ5prkIKp2KXyMJz6l27JL7DhV9oCnnGIQU1vxO0jWbKVmthBegE6OIQODt6S7rNG9zq790GSrGUugSPo08ABFtBLzMr9oLUzbPcdq7RVK93iBOgahN1NsuN0nnLpEI4cjiYkMkN5SO8ZcQ5lTuelnuFg1cJkRLyhTgjLlXeJEEvaZjOmCYcXdloelWjs7Ec@VBV96HYbWtFJT80MCV1sV9WakRz2aOo81eDYQLJq7H5DlwAdmgCjFTv8UtBjQfadhp8AHEAZJRkWTfGkGuILb2gm0tSZ4juA4Oh72dgJRa4HZV9bcGURJt@JmoxnKRrantQGNDQYGnqKcPbdMrKNCQgEywFin5OKxcxXBA5/d1OEFtmHckpdkqygqlFQZO6NgNdm/EuH2bXL6oOzQhCI4h3xAChuHD16F9XkVDPuKEwwj7WsNtdgj6t8tsYoka7doboDgptzMjas7Cqn7Y/jxyqNWsL9A0CdeCV1D2N4ERl72lPLsHoppuQeDA7dcD7ydmplpvAeF7zus4hExl6jIjjjPuA9wwuep5CqO0igHQzjqMEtgwChgGvtmI91bGGqQViDf3iY@J8zNbTq2hr/8cIw3FFPia44yztGE6RudO0QpjqEKrJA2ZOpbxqk4jBOQox9YebS2qGYxqO0793FCbNlN5JZEeHKGGRUww7HUQ4mTnKd2KDZp4eOxQFYgLBKS4P7nE@6cGtGIeUsPkDnph5zgc4b51kNyRBzXT1UJkoumVDft0PYWtSg0Pe6@@v2iQqVRvDzElzPPsZPH@lPV@lt/rIgCAQmIcPY2U5XCsBNA3YuWkqRvRUqxmKan7PciTfZfpNIJmtaW/u@qhCo9X0b3CkNoaYjKg6DGjlGp2qKxWjW1WsQGQrvQb8X6pRz5q34CND4Ove27hxWPJIjzgSV5wFYCE57n2mkeHB86CK7L87D66uHjgQwBxr7vmnZ@cXTy6f6mzUpQ0q5ZBCbE9RzNZMTkZFss73Ug38/LPPX7z84suvNKw3h7B6T4aBgGDa4nFXTE/ORuSvv/n2u@9/ePX6x59@fqPRZ54P8DNvMtJYfIXf4RyUoWrzFw08d8@HMWHTyPqrZvXPL4ZZYdPI@lvprPmYo@ZG1t9LVv9sjNc/MzL/UTD7lyO8/qWR9c9K5XGd1RWDmrebz1@X0zwhEbWtzMIwHZ8InIoQL6zjAmwIQ0U4X0ynIzQnigZ7C6BxWhcgkf6oLK5UiqsTgVY82xruVyZHo0Jd@tqmD/9orPeX827LfgafYi/6nREkqu@4ckKGwu93orvhAUb3RDZwFpWa3A5o2hHRuxiJNhzfOo65L5pP6B4YYIB0w0FREagbIPcW/K9FJmR7ExOUBVa5mMGBc3esg1l2A9kCVDaAQ0dvdnhb2aotVNdafDIpL886ikIqYU0C0PfLp0/xzMfnp/gMXzzB5@fYh8dTfHkJyz4@vcBn59f/AA)

### Explanation

```
0,;         Begin from an empty `sorted` list
i,          For each item in input list:
  :#1,;       Duplicate, and wrap `sorted`'s length
              in a singleton list
              (that is to be used later in a 'fry' structure)

  ns          Push current foreach item, and swap it below the length
  ,           'Fry' the input list's length inside
              (accessed with n; singleton lists only loop once)

              Note: at this point the remaining items on the stack are the `sorted` list and the current item of the outer foreach loop.
    s           Swap outer foreach loop item below the `sorted` list
    ,           Foreach item in the sorted list:
      n           Push current foreach item in `sorted` list
      2,;         Pair (but reversed); to implement a conditional swap
                  if the pair happens to be in decreasing order at any point in our loop
      :           Duplicate it, to perform a conditional check
      ,n_         Dump the pair onto the stack
      T*+         Subtract them

      0s          Swap 0 underneath
      ,,_1_       Repeat n times: drop & push 1
                  So if the left item in the pair > right item in the pair,
                  We would definitely execute the next conditional 1 time.

      ,o_         Execute (0 pr 1 times) based on our previous value: reverse the pair
      ,n_         Dump the pair onto the stack
    _           End foreach loop over sorted list
                (We're now in our 'fry' structure.)
    n           Push the length of our previous `sorted` list
    1+          Add 1 to that
    ,;o         Wrap last n items into a list,
                and reverse it back into the right order
                (Now we have a new `sorted` list for the next iteration of the foreach loop.)
  _           End fry sequence
_           End foreach loop in input list
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 49 Bytes

```
a=>a.map(c=>setTimeout(alert,c-Math.min(...a),c))
```

Basic sleep sort implementation. Takes input as an array and outputs as alerts.

Comment: Won't this fail for negative integers in the array?

Comment: @Shaggy This is accounted for via `-Math.min(...a)`, which, for the case in which the smallest value is -5, would shift all values up by 5, ensuring this still works.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `M`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
lṗ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run?code=l%E1%B9%97&input=%5B4%2C2%2C3%2C1%5D&flags=M)

Port of Adnan's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
lṗ  # Implicit input
l   # Length of input
 ṗ  # Permutations with that length
    # Implicit output of minimum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 14 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 1.75 bytes

```
⇧İ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oenxLAiLCIiLCI5OSwtMiw1Myw0LDY3LDU1LDIzLDQzLDg4LC0yMiwzNiw0NSJd)

Grade up technically doesn't sort the list, but rather gives the position of the first minimum, followed by the position of the second most minimum, followed by the position of the third most minimum and so on.

### Explained

```
⇧İ
⇧  # Grade up the list
 I # and index into the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), <s>99</s> 80 bytes

*-19 thanks to [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/96039/)!*

Unfortuantely Desmos does not have great capabilities for my [favorite sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort), so here is an implementation of **[counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)**!

```
m=A.min
r=[m...A.max]
f(A)=[r[∑_{n=m}^rA[A=n].length=i][1]fori=[1...A.length]]
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wi5kjzppcb?nographpaper)

**How it works:**

\$m\$ is just a shorthand for \$A.\operatorname{min}\$ to shave off a few bytes from the code. Note that we are referring to \$A\$ even when it is not defined in this context, but this still works due to some [wacko variable scoping](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230106/94915).

\$r\$ is also a shorthand for the range \$[m\dots A.\operatorname{max}]\$. This expression appears twice so we can also shave off yet a few more bytes with this.

Next comes the actual sorting procedure:

```
f(A)=[r[∑_{n=m}^rA[A=n].length=i][1]fori=[1...A.length]]
     [                              fori=[1...A.length]]  repeat for i∈[1,A.length]
      r[                        ]                         filter r
        ∑_{n=m}^r                                         sum from min to r
                 A[A=n].length                            # of occurrences of n
                              =i                          sum=i
                                 [1]                      take the first result
```

*Still doesn't make sense?* Let's review the algorithm:

- counting sort: count the occurrences of each value and reassemble them in order

  - # of occurrences is always 0 or 1 since every element is distinct
- instead of reassembling, we **construct the sorted array on the spot**

  - how? *figure out where each element should be*
  - since we know the number of times each element occurs, we can add up the past occurrences to get the sorted index of the current element
  - now we just look for the element with the specified index (and repeat this for every index)

For example:

```
A = [ 3 2 9 5 ]

             i ->  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
             r = [ 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
 A[A=i].length = [ 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 ]  number of occurrences
∑A[A=i].length = [ 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 ]  cumulative sum/new index
```

Now for each index \$i\$ in the final sorted array we look for the first item in \$r\$ for which \$\sum A[A=i].\operatorname{length}=i\$. This gives all the elements in the original list, but in sorted order.

Comment: [80 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dcqsjkoha8)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
Ans→A
cumSum(seq(sum(Ans=I),I,min(Ans),max(Ans
min(ʟA)+seq(sum(Ans<I),I,1,dim(ʟA
```

Counting sort. Takes input in `Ans`. Fails if the range is greater than the list size limit.

---

#### <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```
Ans→A
While 0>min(ΔList(augment(Ans,{max(Ans
randIntNoRep(1,dim(Ans
seq(ʟA(Ans(I)),I,1,dim(Ans
End
Ans
```

Bogosort. Takes input in `Ans`. Only works on calculators where `randIntNoRep(` is supported. For lists with more than one element, you can replace `augment(Ans,{max(Ans` with `Ans` for -5 bytes.

---

#### 63 bytes

```
Prompt A
For(I,1,dim(ʟA
For(J,I,dim(ʟA
ʟA(I→T
If Ans>ʟA(J:Then
ʟA(J→ʟA(I
T→ʟA(J
End
End
End
ʟA
```

Similar method to [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180604/91262), though I'm not sure if it's exactly bubble sort as the elements it compares aren't always adjacent.

---

#### <s>72</s> 71 bytes

```
Ans→A
For(I,1,dim(Ans)-1
min(Ans→ʟB(I
sum(not(cumSum(ʟA=Ans
seq(ʟA(I+(I>Ans)),I,1,dim(ʟA)-1→A
End
Ans(1→ʟB(I:ʟB
```

Selection sort. Takes input in `Ans`. For lists with more than one element, you can replace `Ans(1→ʟB(I:ʟB` with `augment(ʟB,Ans` for -6 bytes.

Comment: I think you can do `Ans→A`

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), <strike>58</strike> 29 bytes

<strike>`r(A,B=[])=A>[] ? (push!(B,popat!(A,argmin(A)));r(A,B)) : B`</strike>

```
!A=A.|>_->popat!(A,argmin(A))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZHBToNAEIbjUZ7iBy-7ZmgKLRU0VOnNZyDErIHWNRQaoIcmvomXXvoEnj35FPo0zkINFw-b-fef75_ZZN9Pr_tSq-PPRZ6rTiFGal0KpFFErk_BjOa0uKEgIJ_ljMKQbZ9mC5oHGSE1F-bmpm1MhgKT4gDHmI6iDJLQz_QmHnlT5vk8Vus-z5VgHJguvKnBe9rJ9deHQ8623hzqppeq3CrHxAZFODMYoXGb8IgfKslU9riwdnm_P5Vmxp8-tzByJoaMn5FZV6ibja5USQgiPB-6omWvEQmt4jSTcbJMM9xD7Pbtiy1WtKt3qrO5rZrNVlcikVLe9biUuMXqtO_WbvhpJ3EyeVs-uct_AgPzfb2uGwhNhYSuYD7HAh5U2xZNB1toiThGYRVVbg2J43Govw)

- an `out-place` selection sort
- shortened <strike>slightly</strike> considerably by @MarcMush

Comment: Slightly simplified [`!A=A.|>_->popat!(A,argmin(A))`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RZAxboNAEEWVMrS5wEC1Gw0WC6wDBVYocwaEopUAayMDFsZFpNwkDY1PkDpVTpGcJjNgi2L1_868P7Paz8vb-WDN9Hf3UJnRQAaFcy-gSFP0Q9QRxrh9Qq0xJBthklA5xGiLsS4RCr4QF3ObiwRpTlGAYkSnaQkSYZ6pNgpVQDydl66Z86QIXAHuggoYn2mvsj9fHnptv3_vh9maQ2s8ji0O4crACq3bhEJ6qERWqpGQ92l_GEiecfPXFqwcx6CkZ5SX89j4ybebZ_nmY_fq74790YyuyNEM-9Z2IpdyYX4fm34AYbGWYDvgv3QAns3pVA8juMJKyDKonbqrnCUxTYv-Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 78 bytes

```
(_+),-(_+)/-$2,$1/-(_+),-\1(_+)\b/-$1$2,-$1/(?<!-)(_+)(_+),\1\b/$1,$1$2/#input
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBCoAwDATfIvbQYkKIZ8GPFBaEIl5EioK/j029zMLM1lLLXl6ziCkRO4XDTEGFf5XVN29NawuNEtdl4OS6X7K2GpS8y3ic13ObAQQ4@oAYsA8)

Essentially a Parallel Bubble-sort. Takes input as Signed Unary. Much of the program is just edge-cases for signed integers, without them this is just:

#### Unsigned, 28 bytes

```
(_+)(_+),\1\b/$1,$1$2/#input
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/XyNeWxOEdWIMY5L0VQx1VAxVjPSVM/MKSkv@/4@P14mPBxFgCkT@BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 125 bytes

```
using System.Linq;x=>{for(int i=0;i<x.Count;i++){int temp=x.GetRange(i,x.Count-i).Min();x[x.IndexOf(temp)]=x[i];x[i]=temp;}};
```

It uses the selection sort. I don't need to return the sorted list, because in C# lists are reference types, so the variable only holds a reference to the actual object, and if I change the object from here, it'll be visible at other places, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321602/why-is-list-when-passed-without-ref-to-a-function-acting-like-passed-with-ref) stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 160 bytes

```
set i 0
time {incr j;set x 0;while \$x<$i {if [lindex $L $i]<[lindex $L $x] {set L [lreplace [linsert $L $x [lindex $L $i]] $j $j]};incr x};incr i} [llength $L]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU1bDoJAEPv3FP3YA6zyNHAEboD7YXCUISshyxI3IZwdR/DDmGnSmU6b@sauI3lUmCON0xlRjCM0cmQyqXCeIEKcZkhEE6TLFmDog@cnYea@ceiKjxigi1fLlnBRoVQszztqy/2NAlQFxab8PYPBvLfX1tFgrw1t9pGc3w1/aQPVCcxSbK3hy7yIz1L/8K0YzTpMfpRlfQM)

Without even thinking on a "standard" method, I implement it by using Insertion Sort.

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 36 bytes

```
{If[#_,Min[_]'$[Remove[_,Min!_]],_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP1fnF9UomBl@7/aMy1aOV7HNzMvOj5WXSU6KDU3vyw1GiyiGB8bqxMfW/s/oCgzryQapCWaK9rSUkfXSMfUWMdEx8xcx9RUxwjINNaxsAAKG@kYm@mYmMZyxcb@BwA)

Selection sort. Recursively sorts the list by concatenating the minimum with the sorted removed list.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>33</strike>32 bytes

```hs
import Data.Set
s=elems.fromList
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRLzi1hKvYNjUnNbdYL60oP9cns7jkf25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQrFCtLGOmY6hjq6pjoGOpSmQrWtobKJjZB77HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript

`for(i=0;i<size;i++){for(j=i+1;j<size;j++){if(num[i]>num[j]){swap=num[j];num[j]=num[i];num[i]=swap;}}}for(i=0;i<size;i++)console.log(num[i])`

Here's an implementation of bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 42 bytes

```
a=>Object.keys(a.reduce((o,k)=>o[k]=o,{}))
```

**Note:** doesn't work for negative numbers.  The iteration order of an object's keys are defined as such in the current [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys), requiring that all numerical indexes are iterated in sorted numerical order first.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
M=Wk§M rm
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=TT1Xa6dNIHJt&input=Wzk5LC0yLDUzLDQsNjcsNTUsMjMsNDMsODgsLTIyLDM2LDQ1XQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 77 bytes

```cs
a=>{for(int@i=0,t;++i<a.Count;)if((t=a[i-1])>a[i]){a[i-1]=a[i];a[i]=t;i=0;}};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU1BasMwELzrFYvpQSJrk9hxmiBLNBQCLbnlkEPwQRglLAQZ7G17MH67K1HoZXdmdmemG/NupOXYMfWh@TjTyA0FthZOYGBxxk73fpBReiOzRtarFTWueO@/AmtFdynZuBvlm1bZuFs1/bEktjoNwzo69TzrRXy7AZ6xIkYH/wP/bVLBdDhgXmJd4RZ3r1jXWEZYJbDfx0uJ1Q639azFSaYIpYUQ14HYnyl4OfJA4VF89hRkhpBh@iku/uk7lg6MhZdscnOmVDQuvw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 9 bytes

`äRm«â-ÍÌ+`

[online-interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=5FJtq-Itzcwr&in=Wzk5LC0yLDUzLDQsNjcsNTUsMjMsNDMsODgsLTIyLDM2LDQ1XQ==)

### Explanation

```
äRm«â-ÍÌ+  ; implicit input
ä          ; duplicate the input
 Rm«       ; get the smallest element
    â      ; push a copy of the element below the list
     -     ; subtract the smallest element from the list
      Í    ; create list with 1's at the positions given by the list
       Ì   ; get the positions of the ones (in ascending order)
        +  ; add back the minimum element
```