# Binary Fibonacci

Tags: code-golf, binary, fibonacci

### Challenge

You need to generate a program or function that takes in a positive integer N, calculates the first N terms of the Fibonacci sequence in binary, concatenates it into a single binary number, converts that number back to decimal, and then outputs the decimal as an integer.

For example

```
1 -> [0] -> 0 to decimal outputs 0
3 -> [0, 1, 1] -> 011 to decimal outputs 3
4 -> [0, 1, 1, 10] -> 01110 to decimal outputs 14
```

You do not need to output the `->`, just the number (e.g. if the user types `4`, just output `14`). The arrows are just to help explain what the program must do.

### Test cases

```
1 -> 0
2 -> 1
3 -> 3
4 -> 14
5 -> 59
6 -> 477
7 -> 7640
8 -> 122253
9 -> 3912117
10 -> 250375522
11 -> 16024033463
12 -> 2051076283353
13 -> 525075528538512
14 -> 134419335305859305
15 -> 68822699676599964537
16 -> 70474444468838363686498
17 -> 72165831136090484414974939
18 -> 147795622166713312081868676669
19 -> 605370868394857726287334099638808
20 -> 4959198153890674493745840944241119317
```

The program must be able to output up to the limit of the language in use. No lookup tables or [common workarounds](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) allowed.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with the shortest number of bytes wins!

Comment: Added test cases from 0 to 20 from https://tio.run/##DYxBCoQwDAC/Ejwl0Ih63vUj4qFWIjlsWrK9CP69dmDmOCW68lWawBea8Sqef6deWv@YsqVYcTvUot8oemSLKSkq0aMf3qZxNJ73ncJCTbKj9ckcYJkCFFerOEBnAOvy2iNoRNRe. Credit to @alephalpha for the program.

Comment: As it hasn't been said yet: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first challenge.

Comment: Where exactly does the language-specific limit apply?  Would a C function that returns a 32-bit integer be allowed?  Like `int32_t binary_concat_Fib(int n)`, which would limit the resulting output value to 2^31-1.  i.e. you get to assume all the concatenated bits fit in an integer.  Or should the function work up to the point where the largest Fibonacci number doesn't fit in an integer on its own, so concatenating the bits takes extended precision?

Comment: @PeterCordes I'd say either is allowed, as long as it's at least int32 or that int.

Comment: And does the "converts to decimal" have to be explicit, calling an integer->string function or writing one yourself?  Concatenating the bits into a single integer gives you a representation of the final value.  If I understand correctly, Dennis's Python answer is returning an integer, leaving it up to the caller to turn that value into a decimal string or do whatever with it.  Integer values in computer languages that support bit-shift operators are naturally binary, not decimal, unless they're stored in strings.  In languages without shifts / bitwise operators, nothing implies any base.

Comment: The output should be an integer

Comment: Ok, so you were just describing it in terms of implementation in a language where you explode each bit to a list element, instead of normal bit shifts / manipulation where the result of packing bits together already is an integer.

Comment: @PeterCordes It goes like this. Calculate fibonacci up to N `4 -> [0, 1, 1, 2]`, change to binary `[0, 1, 1, 10]`, concatenate it like a string `01110`, convert it from base 2 to base 10 `14`

Comment: Well yeah if you had a *string* like `"01110"` then you'd have some conversion to do.  But if you had an *integer* like `0b01110` (note lack of quote marks; I'm using C++ syntax to represent a constant using ASCII digits for base 2, but I'm talking about those bits packed into an integer already), it would already also represent `14` in decimal, and `0xe` in hex.  But it's still stored in memory / a register in binary until you print it to a string.  Dennis's Python answer doesn't have any list->decimal function because it never unpacked the bits in the first place (except to find log2(a).

Comment: Numbers in computers (like an `int` in C) aren't "in decimal" until you print / convert them to strings, unless you're using [binary-coded-decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) or something weird like that.

Comment: Because no one have mentioned that, you can post your challenge in the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) before posting on main. (read the link for more details)

Comment: I would ask that you avoid using "dec" as an abbreviation for "decimal. "Dec" is the name for ten in base 12 which made me confused.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), 64 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,a=0,b=1,r=0:n and f(n-1,b,a+b,r<<len(bin(a))-2|a)or r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBDoMgEAXQdXuK2QnpkAjdEeldhigtif2aiRtjPTt185Zv3bfPgmdrJc3yzaMQWFLPOXnW1EeQYKRi4DxnlkdmHYZ5gskVRqx14Sd2UdJWLkEVpIL3ZDxT8Dbeb6tWbKZ0B2I4yb3ouDZ7drb9AQ)

Comment: Nice, I was just trying to achieve this style.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>7</s>  6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḶÆḞBẎḄ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9qZWxsef//4bi2w4bhuJ5C4bqO4biE////NA)**

#### How?

```
ḶÆḞBẎḄ - Link: integer, n
Ḷ      - lowered range -> [0,1,2,3,4,5,...,n]
 ÆḞ    - Fibonacci (vectorises) -> [0,1,1,2,3,5...,F(n)]
   B   - to binary (vectorises) -> [[0],[1],[1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,0,1],...,B(F(n))]
    Ẏ  - tighten -> [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,...,B(F(n))[0],B(F(n))[1],...]
     Ḅ - from binary -> answer
```

Comment: Messing around with the new quicks, I found that the first *n* Fibonacci numbers can also be found using `Ṛc’SƲƤ` which could be useful for similar sequences.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/), 61 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,a=0,b=1:n and int(f'{a:b}{f(n-1,b,a+b)*2:b}',2)//2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwEADP@oq9JatbatZbIP5llxoVdFtCL6Xk7WkLXoeZmZb5Pdq9tZy@8tNBwEjSjTSFaCA2wMdmn90qUeuavXWBlOSqeOGdOGLse255LGC7CkXs9fSBgAPG82kq/9wiV@gecCywOmwb)

Answer (score 8):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
ḋṁḋ↑Θİf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GO7oc7G4Hko7aJ52Yc2ZD2//9/IwMA)

#### Explanation

```
ḋṁḋ↑Θİf                              4
     İf    The Fibonacci numbers     [1,1,2,3,5,8..]
    Θ      Prepends 0                [0,1,1,2,3,5..]
   ↑     Take n elements from list   [0,1,1,2]
  ḋ        Convert to binary digits  [[0],[1],[1],[1,0]]
 ṁ       Map function then concat    [0,1,1,1,0]
ḋ        Convert from base 2         14
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :)

Answer (score 7):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 397 bytes

```
>,[<++++++[->--------<]>>[->++++++++++<]>[-<+>]<<[->+<],]>+[-<<+>>[-[->+<]<<[->+>+<<]<[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]>>[-<<+>>]>]]<<[->+>>>>>+<<<<<<]>[-<+>]>+>>+>>>+<[[->-[<<]>]>[[-]<<<<<<<[->>[-<+>>+<]>[-<+>]<<<]<[->+>>>>>+<<<<<<]>[-<+>]>[-<+>]>[->>[-<+<<+>>>]<[->+<]<]>+>[-]>>+>]<<<<<[[->++>+>++<<<]>[-<+>]<<]>>>]>[-]<<<[-]<<[-]<<->[>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>>>]<+[->++++++[-<++++++++>]<.<<<+]
```

Well, that was fun!

Takes ASCII input (e.g. `11`), outputs result in ASCII.

Note: to try this online, make sure you set the cell size to 32 bits (on the right side of the webpage). **If you do not enter an input, your browser might crash.**

The interpreter cannot handle input of `11` and higher because it only supports up to 32 bits.

[Try it on copy.sh](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=PixbPCsrKysrK1stPi0tLS0tLS0tPF0-PlstPisrKysrKysrKys8XT5bLTwrPl08PFstPis8XSxdPitbLTw8Kz4-Wy1bLT4rPF08PFstPis-Kzw8XTxbLT4rPis8PF0-Wy08Kz5dPj5bLTw8Kz4-XT5dXTw8Wy0-Kz4-Pj4-Kzw8PDw8PF0-Wy08Kz5dPis-Pis-Pj4rPFtbLT4tWzw8XT5dPltbLV08PDw8PDw8Wy0-PlstPCs-Pis8XT5bLTwrPl08PDxdPFstPis-Pj4-Pis8PDw8PDxdPlstPCs-XT5bLTwrPl0-Wy0-PlstPCs8PCs-Pj5dPFstPis8XTxdPis-Wy1dPj4rPl08PDw8PFtbLT4rKz4rPisrPDw8XT5bLTwrPl08PF0-Pj5dPlstXTw8PFstXTw8Wy1dPDwtPls-KysrKysrKysrKzxbLT4tWz4rPj5dPlsrWy08Kz5dPis-Pl08PDw8PF0-Pj5dPCtbLT4rKysrKytbLTwrKysrKysrKz5dPC48PDwrXQ$$)

### Explanation

```
>,[<++++++[->--------<]>>[->++++++++++<]>[-<+>]<<[->+<],]>+
```

Get decimal input and add one (to mitigate off-by-one)

```
[-<<+>>[-[->+<]<<[->+>+<<]<[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]>>[-<<+>>]>]]
```

Generate  fibonacci numbers on the tape.

```
<<[->+>>>>>+<<<<<<]>[-<+>]>+>>+>>>+<
```

Set up for the incoming binary concatenation loop

---

So the cells contain the value, starting from the first position,

```
1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | ... | f_n | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | f_n | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0...
```

Look at these cells:

```
f_n | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | f_n | 1
```

I'll label this:

```
num | sum | cat | 0 | pow | 0 | num | pow
```

`pow` is there to find the maximal power of 2 that is strictly greater than `num`. `sum` is the concatenation of numbers so far. `cat` is the power of 2 that I would need to multiply the `num` in order to concatenate `num` in front of the `sum` (so I would be able to simply add).

---

```
[[->-[<<]>]>
```

**Loop: Check whether `f_n` is strictly less than `pow`.**

**Truthy:**

```
[[-]<<<<<<<[->>[-<+>>+<]>[-<+>]<<<]<[->+>>>>>+<<<<<<]>[-<+>]>[-<+>]>[->>[-<+<<+>>>]<[->+<]<]>+>[-]>>+>]
```

Zero out junk. Then, add `num` * `cat` to `sum`. Next, load the next Fibonacci number (= `f_(n-1)`; if it doesn't exist, exit loop) and set `cat` to `cat` * `pow`. Prepare for next loop (zero out more junk, shift scope by one).

**Falsey:**

```
<<<<<[[->++>+>++<<<]>[-<+>]<<]
```

Set `pow` to 2 * `pow`, restore `num`.

```
]
```

Repeat until there is no Fibonacci number left.

---

```
>[-]<<<[-]<<[-]<<->[>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>>>]<+[->++++++[-<++++++++>]<.<<<+]
```

Clean garbage. Take each digit of the resulting number and output each (in ascii).

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
ÆMgX ¤Ã¬Í
```

[Run it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=xk1nWCCkw6zN&input=NA==)

### Explanation:

```
ÆMgX ¤Ã¬Í
Æ     Ã     | Iterate X through the range [0...Input]
 MgX        |   Xth Fibonacci number
     ¤      |   Binary
       ¬    | Join into a string
        Í   | Convert into a base-2 number
```

Comment: Bah! Beat me to it!

Comment: @Shaggy I knew this one was going to be a race against you :P

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 22 bytes

```
JU2VQ=+Js>2J)is.BM<JQ2
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JU2VQ%3D%2BJs%3E2J%29is.BM%3CJQ2&input=32&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
JU2VQ=+Js>2J)is.BM<JQ2
JU2                       Set J = [0, 1].
   VQ       )             <Input> times...
     =+Js>2J              ... add the last 2 elements of J and put that in J.
                  <JQ     Take the first <input> elements...
               .BM        ... convert each to binary...
              s           ... concatenate them...
             i       2    ... and convert back to decimal.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>70</strike> <strike>65</strike> <strike>58</strike> <strike>57</strike> 55 bytes

- thanks to Shaggy for reducing 2 bytes ('0b+C-0 to '0b'+C)

```javascript
f=(n,a=C=0,b=1)=>--n?f(n,b,a+b,C+=b.toString(2)):'0b'+C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBLbsMwDET3vUgs2A5EUtSngNKFj9ATWGkcpAjkIjF6fYfqrtJGBB6pGXK@59/5eX7cfrYxr1@XfV9il4c5TlEPKYKKp3HMH4uwNMx9GqY@puO2fm6PW752qNT7QadDP@3nNT/X@@V4X6/d0snHqNXbf4gCoYYkkGpoyqSpKQvlUFMr1DhXYyfYWdMs4Ys0InJjGsomARCgEQMtPWRNjhmx6ZZrwWo0msjYRhjK4agZtLPoiVprKCmwGBR9z@QZWpe/UMgYCEVCs@cgbzNWUrLeI9oQrLMcpBgmp/YX)

Comment: You can ditch the `-0` at the end to save another 2 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 38 bytes

```perl6
{:2([~] (0,1,*+*...*)[^$_]>>.base(2))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2spII7ouVkHDQMdQR0tbS09PT0szOk4lPtbOTi8psThVw0hTs/Z/cWKlQpqGSrymQlp@kYKhnp6hgfV/AA)

Comment: Note that this starts to get noticeably slower with inputs above 200. It takes about 8 seconds to generate the output with an input of 1000. (20 seconds if you include printing it)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
LÅfbJC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f53BrWpKX8///xgA)

---

1-indexed.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 27 bytes

```
JU2V-Q2=aJ+eJ@J_2)is.BM<JQ2
```

[**Test suite**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JU2V-Q2%3DaJ%2BeJ%40J_2%29is.BM%3CJQ2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19%0A20&debug=0)

Python 3 translation:

```
Q=eval(input())
J=list(range(2))
for i in range(Q-2):
    J.append(J[-1]+J[-2])
print(int(''.join(map("{0:b}".format,J[:Q])),2))
```

---

### <s>37 bytes</s>

```
J[Z1)W<lJQ=aJ+eJ@J_2)Ig1QZ.?ijkm.BdJ2
```

**[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%5BZ1%29W%3ClJQ%3DaJ%2BeJ%40J_2%29Ig1QZ.%3Fijkm.BdJ2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A3%0A4%0A10%0A32&debug=0)**

Python 3 translation:

```
Q=eval(input())
J=[0,1]
while len(J)<Q:
    J.append(J[-1]+J[-2])
if 1>=Q:
    print(0)
else:
    print(int(''.join(map("{0:b}".format,J)),2))
```

Answer (score 2):

## x86, <s>37</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

**Changelog**

- -13 by using [`bsr`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BSR.html). Thanks Peter Cordes!
- -2 by [zeroing registers with `mul`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147775/17360).
- -1 by using a while loop instead of `loop` and `push`/`pop` `ecx` (credit Peter Cordes).

Input in `edi`, output in `edx`.

```
.section .text
.globl main
main:
        mov     $5, %edi            # n = 5

start:
        dec     %edi                # Adjust loop count
        xor     %ebx, %ebx          # b = 0
        mul     %ebx                # a = result = 0
        inc     %ebx                # b = 1

fib:
        add     %ebx, %eax          # a += b
        xchg    %eax, %ebx          # swap a,b
        bsr     %eax, %ecx          # c = (bits of a) - 1
        inc     %ecx                # c += 1
        sal     %cl, %edx           # result >>= c
        add     %eax, %edx          # result += a

        dec     %edi                # n--; do while(n)
        jnz     fib 

        ret
```

Objdump:

```
00000005 <start>:
   5:   4f                      dec    %edi
   6:   31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
   8:   f7 e3                   mul    %ebx
   a:   43                      inc    %ebx

0000000b <fib>:
   b:   01 d8                   add    %ebx,%eax
   d:   93                      xchg   %eax,%ebx
   e:   0f bd c8                bsr    %eax,%ecx
  11:   41                      inc    %ecx
  12:   d3 e2                   shl    %cl,%edx
  14:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
  16:   4f                      dec    %edi
  17:   75 f2                   jne    b <fib>
  19:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: Use `lea` to shift-and-add in fib2.  Also, extracting each bit one at a time is unnecessary.  Use `bsr %eax, %ecx` to find the number of bits in the binary representation, and use a shift by CL / or to merge, like Dennis's Python answer is doing.

Comment: @PeterCordes the source of this convoluted method is the result of a headache and a misinterpretation of the problem spec to use base 10 instead of base 2. I will fix.

Comment: Heh, see my comments on the question.  It drives me nuts when people think that integers are "in decimal" because that's how they wrote the constant.  This fuzzy thinking may be due to golfing and other languages that have functions to convert an integer to a list / array of elements, 1 per bit, and then using list manipulation instead of bitwise operations on integers.  Although I'm not sure how the "base 10" part of the problem statement got you, more like the way the examples were written with all bits separated leads you to unnecessary unpacking.  Headache would do it, though :/

Comment: You need `cl` for shift counts, so take your loop counter in a different reg (like `%edi`) and use `dec %edi / jnz` (3 bytes in 32-bit code, 4 bytes in 64-bit).  In 32-bit code, that saves 1 byte total from dropping the push/pop ecx.  Don't fall into the trap of using `loop` when it makes the problem harder, not easier.  (Your calling convention is already custom, clobbering `%ebx`, so don't call your function `main`)  You might be able to return in EAX while still taking advantage of 1-byte `xchg`, no need to be non-standard if you don't need to.

Comment: @PeterCordes aw I got so excited to use `loop`. :(

Comment: You can replace the extra `inc %ecx` of the shift count with an extra left-shift as you add, using `lea (%eax, %edx, 2), %edx`.  Neutral in bytes for 32-bit, saves one for x86-64.  But saves an instruction.

Comment: Every time I end up using `loop` in code golf, I feel dirty.  Well not quite, but disappointed that I couldn't find an equally small implementation that avoided that slow instruction; outside of code golf, [`loop` is one of my pet peeves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881279/how-exactly-does-the-x86-loop-instruction-work/46881622#46881622).  I *wish* it was fast on modern CPUs, because it would be very nice for extended-precision loops without partial-flag stalls, but it's not and should be considered only as an obscure size optimization instruction that makes your code slow.

Comment: re: result in EAX, no nvm, `result` stays in the same register the whole time, and you need EAX to be one of the Fibonacci registers for `xchg`.  So returning in EAX to make this MS `__fastcall` would cost an extra byte.

Comment: Anyway, nice job.  Other than push/pop/loop -> dec/jnz, I don't see any savings, just the LEA speedup that's neutral in code-size.  I'd always wondered if there was ever a real use case for the `xor`/`mul` trick to zero three registers (do you ever need that many zeroes?), but using that as part of creating a `1` makes it more sensible.

Comment: @PeterCordes Now that I think about it, working with `ax` is like working with `ah` and `al` at the same time. I wonder if there are any cool tricks involving that.

Comment: Yup, sure.  integer -> 2-digit decimal ASCII number with `div %bl` / `add $0x3030, %ax` ([especially in 16-bit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129794/displaying-time-in-assembly)) to give you a 2-byte ASCII string which stores to memory in printing order (10's place first, in AL).  You can even use `aam` to divide AL (rather than AX) by an immediate (default is 10), but the results go in opposite registers from `div`.  Or sometimes `lodsw` / `xchg al,ah`, maybe as part of [sorting byte elements](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149038/30206), again especially in x86-16.

Answer (score 2):

## J, 36 Bytes

```
3 :'#.;<@#:"0]2}.(,{:+_2&{)^:y _1 1'
```

#### Explanation:

```
3 :'#.;<@#:"0]2}.(,{:+_2&{)^:y _1 1' | Explicit function
                 (,{:+_2&{)^:y _1 1  | Make n fibonacci numbers, with _1 1 leading
              2}.                    | Drop the _1 1
       <@#:"0]                       | Convert each item to binary and box
      ;                              | Unbox and join
    #.                               | Convert back from binary
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>89</strike> <strike>76</strike> 75 bytes

```
f=0:scanl(+)1f
foldr1(\x y->y+x*2*2^floor(logBase 2.read.show$y)).(`take`f)
```

Ungolfed version:

```
import Data.Bits

fib = 0:scanl (+) 1 fib

catInt :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
catInt x y = x' + y where
    position = floor $ succ $ logBase 2 $ realToFrac y
    x' = shift x position

answer :: Integer -> Integer
answer n = foldr1 catInt fib' where
    fib' = take n fib
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and Haskell golfing in particular! A shorter way to generate an infinite list of Fibonacci numbers is `f=0:scanl(+)1f` (taken from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89/56433)). Functions can be anonymous, so you can drop the leading `g=`, see our [Guide to Ggolfing Rules in Haskell](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11935/56433).

Comment: Thanks! That compensates for some of the longer functions used. I spent a while trying to find a way to implement bit-shifting in a more concise way, but came up short.

Comment: You can replace `$realToFrac y` with `.read.show$y` for one byte

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>26</s> 22 bytes

*4 bytes saved thanks to @H.PWiz*

```apl
{2⊥∊2∘⊥⍣¯1¨1∧+∘÷\~⍵↑1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24Rqo0ddSx91dBk96pgBYvUuPrTe8NAKw0cdy7WBQoe3x9Q96t36qG2iYS1Qg8KhFY96NxsaAAA)

Comment: [Save 2 bytes on the fibonacci bit](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24Rqo0ddSx91dBk96pgBYvUuPrTe8NCKw9sNH3Ws0AYKHt4eY/iobfKj3q36hrVAPQqHVjzq3WxoAAA)

Comment: [Even shorter](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24Rqo0ddSx91dBk96pgBYvUuPrTe8NAKw0cdy7WBQoe3x9Q96t36qG2iYS1Qg8KhFY96NxsaAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 59 bytes

```
n->fromdigits(concat([binary(fibonacci(i))|i<-[0..n-1]]),2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcwxDoMwDEDRq1hMthSjUlWdWi6CGEIqIw84kZsFibuHLH94wy/RlffSBL7QjGfxfPx01/rHlC3FisumFv1E0S1bTElRiS798PIYR@NpXSk8qUl2tD6ZArxfAYqr1Q4D8NwjaETUbg)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 55 bytes

Prompts for screen input of integer.

```
v←b←0 1⋄⍎∊(⎕-2)⍴⊂'v←v,c←+/¯2↑v⋄b←b,((1+⌊2⍟c)⍴2)⊤c⋄'⋄2⊥b
```

APL+WIN's maximum integer precision is 17 and integer limit is of the order of 10E300 therefore the maximum input number is 55 and the result is: 1.2492739026634838E300

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 94 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,a=[0,1]:n>len(a)and f(n,a+[sum(a[-2:])])or int(''.join(bin(v)[2:]for v in a[:n]),2)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpLDoMwDEXRrWSGraYVn44iwUasDIwgKggcBBSpq3fN4E3uedvv/GRpVFO78NoP7MRzS6WvYpBuGQUYWQaXwPqDju8KTM86RIyYdzfJCUXxmvMk0NsuJLNkcpk5piARfY267fc1wRtR9Q8)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ḶÆḞBFḄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm2H2x7umOfk9nBHy////00A)

`Ḷ`owered range -> *n*th `ÆḞ`ibonacci number -> from dec to `B`inary -> `F`latten -> from `Ḅ`inary to dec

Comment: Didn't understand this language but I thought the output is not always correct. e.g. Input `10` and you will get an `16024033463`, it is incorrect (correct answer is `250375522`).

Comment: @AbrahamChin [Input `10` returns `250375522`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm2H2x7umOfk9nBHy////w0NAA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Comment: [Equivalent, duplicate answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160860/66833), just a heads up

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 21 bytes

```
0li:"yy+]xx&h"@B]&hXB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yAn00qpslI7tqJCLUPJwSlWLSPC6f9/QwMA)

#### Explanation

```
0l        % Push 0, then 1 (initial terms of the Fibonacci sequence)
i:"       % Do n times, where n is the input
  yy+     %   Duplicate top two numbers and push their sum
  ]       % End
xx        % Delete the last two results. The stack now contains the
          % first n Fibonacci numbers, starting at 0
&h        % Concatenate all numbers into a row vector
"         % For each
  @       %   Push current number
  B       %   Convert to binary. Gives a vector of 0 and 1
]         % End
&h        % Concatenate all vectors into a row vector
XB        % Convert from binary to decimal. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jotlin](https://github.com/jrtapsell/jotlin), 59 bytes

```
g(l(0,1)){l(a.sum(),a[0])}.take(this).j(""){a[0].s(2)}.i(2)
```

### Test Program

```
data class Test(val input: Int, val output: Long)

val tests = listOf(
    Test(1, 0),
    Test(2, 1),
    Test(3, 3),
    Test(4, 14),
    Test(5, 59),
    Test(6, 477),
    Test(7, 7640),
    Test(8, 122253),
    Test(9, 3912117),
    Test(10, 250375522)
)
fun Int.r() = g(l(0,1)){l(a.sum(),a[0])}.take(this).j(""){a[0].s(2)}.i(2)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for (r in tests) {
        println("${r.input.r()} vs ${r.output}")
    }
}
```

It supports up to 10, changing `.i(2)` for `.toLong(2)` would support up to 14 if needed

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 25 bytes

```
2(#.;)<@#:@(1#.<:!|.)\@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqhDoAgFAXQzldcIcDb2BsSn@j4EJuTicVgMei3o4bTzt7KiVEQ8GnRGR4oZSPZ9YaTdDfTnCs3Upphy18tPB5BOZVal@2A81x0IEyCyojhai8)

### Explanation

```
2(#.;)<@#:@(1#.<:!|.)\@i.  Input: n
                       i.  Range [0, n)
                     \@    For each prefix
                  |.         Reverse
                 !           Binomial coefficient (vectorized)
               <:            Decrement
            1#.              Sum
        #:                   Convert to binary
      <                      Box
    ;                        Link. Join the contents in each box
2 #.                         Convert to decimal from base 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 86 bytes

```
def f(N):
 a,b,l=0,1,''
 for _ in range(N):l+=format(a,'b');a,b=b,a+b
 return int(l,2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc0xDgIhEIXhfk8xDRkmOyaCnQaP4BUMBFATnN0QLDw9QmX78v15@7c9Nzn1HlOGrG90XsBz4OKObBhxgbxVuMNLoHp5pCnK6sb49k17xoB0GYEL7NewQE3tU2Xwpgtb6rOWf23Ymnmx1ylQ2QiHK6iIoLRw1kJE/Qc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 113 bytes

```
D,f,@@@@*,V$2D+G1+dAppp=0$Qp{f}p
D,k,@,¿1=,1,bM¿
D,g,@,¿1_,1_001${f},1¿{k}
D,w,@,BBbR
D,l,@,ßR€gp€w@0b]@¦+VcG2$Bb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BaoQwFIbXySlEAoUawThdtVhSKwilXVSKdDPIaFQyYzWgM0NH3PQisyh01TsIzk16kKbPThbh53v/93grIZTSOqAF5fAuaUzcwAqZJe6UUp5DnlVfDAoHdEM5nUbmUUbTp2kEUp5JQlniOIxAj7Jp7DcDzPYw8/00glhBPB2jn4/vUsG350665NOXFWehS/xU3xgvedvJusRQ3tb5bjUbGJkXpuDr3UzXjazhPoCwoD93Boy4SB8XJMFo4d6fjq@g2LeGCTzm4cPsHeg1OK4TGSLe/ssVRv4yJH6G0fTZz3uHWuur30Z1sqlbbdvyTVUykx3EVuWZLN69wx8)

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 124 Bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LczLCsIwEIXhV8lioDO0WCu6itF3SZrQgExiL7gIffY4Sjdn8cP58pTr/Zllw8ZujYlVQOAOojl3YE3TUFHxlx4QqYA9mdE7GxnntPGIOX0Ql/e84o3agfqLPKk/ApE@sHYQjPTuX4sv3k1JCSEQ/uteA15J1y8)

So I was looking for a way to output fibonacci numbers using the series, until I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding). It turns out you can calculate the fibonacci series via rounding, so I tried the challenge with a recursive function.

I found the approach of "rounding" really interesting, also a professor showed me this a while ago.

**Code**

```
function f($n,$i=0,$b=''){ if($n>$i){$b.=
decbin(round(pow((sqrt(5)+1)/2,$i)/sqrt(5)));f($n,$i+1,$b);}else{echo bindec($b);}}
```

**Explanation**

```
function f($n,$i=0,$b=''){           #the function starts with $i=0, our nth-fib number
if($n>$i){                           #it stops once $n (the input) = the nth-fib
    $b.=decbin(                      #decbin returns an integer as bin, concatenates
        round(pow((sqrt(5)+1)/2,$i)/sqrt(5))    
                                       #the formula, basically roundign the expression
        );                           #it returns the (in this case) $i-th fib-number   
    f($n,$i+1,$b);                   #function is called again for the next index
}else{                               #and the current string for fibonacci

    echo bindec($b);                 #"echo" the result, bindec returns the base 10
                                     #value of a base 2 number
}
}
```

Also check [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600041/php-fibonacci-sequence) the best answer refers to the same article on Wikipedia.

Comment: Interesting way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü1∞╓♪εw≤+
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8131ecd60dee77f32b&i=1%0A%0A2%0A%0A3%0A%0A4%0A%0A5%0A%0A6%0A%0A7%0A%0A8%0A%0A9%0A%0A10%0A%0A11%0A%0A12%0A%0A13%0A%0A14%0A%0A15%0A%0A16%0A%0A17%0A%0A18%0A%0A19%0A%0A20%0A&a=1&m=1)

### Unpacked (10 bytes) and explanation:

```
vr{|5|Bm|B
v             Decrement integer from input. Stax's Fibonacci sequence starts with 1 :(
 r            Integer range [0..n).
  {    m      Map a block over each value in an array.
   |5           Push nth Fibonacci number.
     |B         Convert to binary.
        |B    Implicit concatenate. Convert from binary. Implicit print.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 65 bytes

```julia
f(n)=n<2?n:f(n-1)+f(n-2)
n->parse(BigInt,prod(bin.(f.(0:n-1))),2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxCoMwFEbhuXmKIg73UhXN0CE0Frr1HbooJuEW@Q1p@vxRp3OG7/tfZbqXYGcXBMUT2OKhnzDHtgPfzmhWaMc4pZ@jl4Q3chPTttAs6Mh31JuTMjeai8Oi/JauYgeje3WJSZBXUFXLJ9cUSJgrVgcrOw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `project-euler.025`, 37 bytes

```
[ iota [ fib >bin ] map-concat bin> ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcw9DsIwDEDhvafwAWhUKrGA1BWxsCCmKINruRB@kuC4Epw@BBhYnz69CUmjlONht9@u4Y56hsyPmQNxhiTxwqQtzzcW0/WrLzAJJbP8neGnCn44q76S@KA/KBhOdbNpmr4Du1yMrljwUREsTH6EYfQBXLWppRgIFWoYwJVaICvS1ZQ3)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 44 bits<sup>1</sup>, 5.5 [bytes](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md)

```
ʁ∆FbfB
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#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)

### Explained

```
ʁ∆FbfB
ʁ      # range [0, input)
 ∆F    # 0-indexed fibonacci number of each
   bf  # convert each to binary and flatten the list
     B # convert that from binary
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 61 bytes

```ruby
->n,a=0,b=1,s=""{s+="%b"%a;a,b=b,a+b;(n-=1)>0?redo:s.to_i(2)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JVDLTtxAEDzDV1hGaEEYNP2cHtAsH5JEyIZFyQUi1hwi47/IIQe@jh/ZdM/6MFPuqequ6rf36c/huR6uty/DWNMwVRj2te@X/VXtz6f@fLwbvTgN49V0d/FyXeFym@7fdk@vt/ub@fXh1wVerofl9AS6uu3ScHqCAcABBSAH3CrsSAJJcaSBOGeHOWBWDrE1KiJKCEvrUAABgggp/lESZRHEqLSpoAk5EbGGCJoBTAIpKxpRawXNjbg4tCZkAq3D0RwxQwlqEpPiZzw1t2qGqKVoVil@sVDz0gLkxJnjcxYZKakpF4v3YyoEFSMA0lQSm0/hkrlQrACOYX0JRRSdqRmIAJOBeZ@sqo3WtqDJ5yavU2GTnNGjZY@c3BKZpZiJbT9cpEAx8IglqdsrlFnMmczIAJ4ztrne7MbHn93yMQ@7j@73@7zv@rPl@dv8o9Zdd99tvj7/brrbuP9t1u/z2TL7WbeBgrX26@E/)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>244</s> <s>180</s> 179 bytes

```r
i=ifelse;g=function(n)i(n<3,1,g(n-1)+g(n-2))
a=scan(,"");i(a==1,0,sum(2^(which(rev(unlist(sapply(g(2:a-1),function(x)(y=rev(as.numeric(intToBits(x))))[which(!!y)[1]:32]))>0))-1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PczBDoIwEATQu38Bp91YDZSLAevBb/BGMGmaApvAQmhR@fpaYuJc5jCTt4RAilo7OFt1ql3ZeJoYGAn4WohcdMCnHI97ScSDVs5oBpGmWBFopXKRCbeOIJ/w7sn0sNgXrDyQ8@D0PA8bdCBLHRHx5z8Im9qP2p15He1CBoj9Y7qTd3GNqX9akmxY501ZyAbxliFGBzFcwhc)

Saved some bytes by concatenating numeric vectors, not strings. Bloody special case for 0!

Comment: Functions are acceptable. Also it is much more efficient to shift the result left by the number of bits then to bother with numeric vectors. See my or Dennis's python answer. This has the added benefit of handling the 0 case.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4024/tips-for-golfing-in-r R golfing is too much for me :/

Comment: @qwr The answer is not a function; I am creating a helper function because it must be `sapply`’d to a vector due to the fact that it is recursive. It cannot be all wrapped into one line. As you see, the programme prompts for user’s input and then returns the answer. One byte can be saved by creating a shortcut for `ifelse`. And... we can remove `,""` from `scan`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 88 bytes

```
def f(n):
 a,b,r=0,1,"0"
 for _ in range(n-1):a,b=b,a+b;r+=bin(a)[2:]
 print int(r,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 74 bytes

```python
w='';a,b=0,1
exec('w+=bin(a)[2:];a,b=b,a+b;'*int(input()))
print(int(w,2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BDsIgEEX3c4ruBiwmzADF2tSLGBfFNLEb2hhM9fQouHr/5f/JbJ/0WKPJeR8Rh0mFUSuC@T3fBe7tGJYoJnnl8612QU1tGPCwxCSWuL2SkFLC9vx7ErtiKTMiAjXHS6OBCwhMgQFbzYIrdD10hdZ78CX4zmo41QkzOwN9veqJiTyQLsZOG@8cM/yeZNJf)

Ungolfed:

```python
w = ''
a, b = 0, 1
for _ in ' '*int(input()):  # for 0 to input:
    w += bin(a)[2:]         # append next fib. number as binary 
    a, b = b, a + b         #     without leading 0b
print(int(w,2))             # convert whole binary number to decimal int
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 60 bytes

```julia
f(n,a=0,b=1,r=big(0))=n<1?r:f(n-1,b,a+b,r<<length(bin(a))|a)
```

Inspired by Dennis's bit fiddling python answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxDsIwDADAmb4CVR1sYaSEgaGKxUe6xKIpRpGprLDx99Bb7/2tmu@9FzDKHEg4krPoBgGRLcWHz8ddIwnli5CnVFfb2gtEDTLiL2MvHz8rh/kWhtPuaq0ajJMubYICijjisNqz/wE)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 75 bytes

Non-recursive solution. (Doesn't beat the recursive one)

```javascript
n=>"0b"+[...Array(n)].map(c=>(c=a,a=b,b+=c,c).toString(2),a=0,b=1).join``-0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdBLTsMwEADQfU9hZUOspKk/cZIiuYgt2y4REk7qVimpHSVOgQOwQ@ICcACu1YsEu6USFW0seTPzxjOetdiKtmjK2oyVXsh@yXvFZx7KveA@iqLbphGvvoIP0UbUfsFn9opQ8DzMA16EBYyMnpumVCufQBtHYc4xjNa6VI@PY9TLrag6YST3S1V3JpQvtSyMXISNbLvK8OUhDiGfFVq1upJRpVe@/5vm/Fhw4@0@34B37e2@3oEHg31Z4IHdxzfwggOHo9Gxnw8ABiFA4PTAv4BYgIcAtYAOgdi9EA8AZgGbDoDEgjhNL4PUgjSJ0UWQuRkIIYxeAFP3iykmGKdnAUYWEIZoyhgh54DbJE4QiRGlcUL/A7dJghhGaUIySvejnAC3SWZ7uBYZoxmzJXA0mYCFlq26MuBZN09Ab2XjbC4L0bUS6CW4m4Oq3JRGmFKr/gc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
LÆFḃJḂ
```

Port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

##### Explanation

```python
LÆFḃJḂ  # Implicit input                              Input: 4
L       # Lowered range: push [0..input)              Stack: [0, 1, 2, 3]
 ÆF     # nth Fibonacci number (vectorises)           Stack: [0, 1, 1, 2]
   ḃ    # Convert to a binary string (vectorises)     Stack: ["0", "1", "1", "10"]
    J   # Join into a single string                   Stack: "01110"
     Ḃ  # Convert from binary                         Stack: 14
        # Implicit output                            Output: 14
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]