# A factorization game

Tags: code-golf, math

## Input

A single integer \$1 \leq x \leq 10^{15}\$.

## Output

The maximum number of distinct positive integers that have the product \$x\$.

## Examples

Input: 1099511627776. Output: 9.  One possible optimal list of factors is: (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 4096).

Input: 127381. Output 4. One possible optimal list of factors is: (1, 17, 59, 127).

Related to this [old question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104707/list-all-multiplicative-partitions-of-n?rq=1).

Comment: Could you add a few more test cases? (Preferably of reasonable size.)

Comment: Given your comments on most answers: if you're looking for efficient code instead, this should definitely not be tagged as `code-golf`. You may consider either `fastest-code` or `fastest-algorithm` for an upcoming challenge. If you really wanted all answers to work in a limited time within the specified range, it should have been explicitly mentioned. (And I would have recommended a smaller range so that it does not conflict with `code-golf` entirely.)

Comment: @Arnauld No  I am careful to make it code-golf and no one is judged for that. It would just be cool if the code could run for the input ranges specfied.

Comment: Quoting xnor: [If it's not mandatory, answers won't do it](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8066/58563).

Comment: This challenge amounts to factoring integers into distinct elements of OEIS A050376 I believe.

Comment: @HaraldKorneliussen I do not think that works for n=225 (as far as I see, it is 9*25, but the output is 4 as 1*3*5*15 works as well), but I might be (and likely am)  completely wrong.

Comment: For `x=1, 2, ...` I get `f(x)=1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3` which I do not find in OEIS. It is clear enough that records will appear for factorial numbers `x`. For example the smallest `x` such that `f(x)=13` will be `13!`. I guess `f` depends only on the exponents of the prime factorization. So to find `f(13^4*19^7*29^2)` we might simplify to `f(2^7*3^4*5^2)`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 52 bytes

```
Max[Length/@Cases[Subsets@Divisors@#,{a__}/;1a==#]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zexItonNS@9JEPfwTmxOLU4Org0qTi1pNjBJbMsszi/qNhBWac6MT6@Vt/aMNHWVjk2Vu1/QFFmXomCQ3q0oZG5sYVh7P//AA)

*4-bytes saved thanks to @attinat*

Here is also a **153 bytes** version that calculates `1099511627776` and `10^15`

```
Max[Length/@Table[s=RandomSample@Flatten[Table@@@FactorInteger[#]];Last@Select[Times@@@TakeList[s,#]&/@IntegerPartitions@Length@s,DuplicateFreeQ],5!]]+1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7RCoIwFEB/pRB6STADlQjhPoQQGFj5NvZws8scbTO2G/T3S6rnc@AcizySRdYDRlXHE75FS07xmEGPN0Mi1Bd098le0T4NQWOQmZz4QgBocODJHx2TIi8SKfctBoYrGRpY9NpSmK0eH9TqwCKkiVxl8Pc79KxZTy7ALwohPbyeZp5hajzRWabFUsp1voqd144XoES@2e2KPC@3VVWVMsYP)

The result for `10^15` is **12**

> {1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 16, 25, 40, 50, 100, 125, 250}

Comment: Crashes with 1099511627776

Comment: @Anush It doesn't crash. Just needs memory. You didn't say anything about memory limitations. This is code golf

Comment: Yes I realise. It just would be nice if you could actually run the code the input ranges specified in the question.

Comment: @Anush This is code-golf. Not nice answers. Please specify your criteria. An answer is either valid or not. I think the problem here is the question... Maybe you should change it to "most sufficient algorithm"

Comment: @Anush I made an edit in my answer and added one more version which is really fast and efficient in case you want to check it

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zexItonNS@9JEPfwTmxOLU4Org0qTi1pNjBJbMsszi/qNhBWac6MT6@Vt/aMNHWVjk2Vu1/QFFmXomCQ3q0oZG5sYVh7P//AA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online") using `Cases`

Comment: and [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zexItonNS@9JEPfwTmxOLU4Org0qTi1pNghKDEvPdVBWac6MT6@Vt/aMNHWVjk2Vu1/QFFmXomCQ3q0kVHs//8A "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online") with `Range` instead of `Divisors`, though it's almost unusable

Comment: How does the 153 byte version work?

Comment: @Anush it is easy to make it work very fast for numbers like `1099511627776` which have only one prime factor (`2^40`). The case of `10^15` which has 2 prime factors is more difficult and that is why this algorithm works on a statistical sample of the permutations

Comment: @J42161217 How do you know the answer is optimal when you take a sample?

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 38 bytes

```
(c=n=#;If[i∣n,n/=i,--c]~Do~{i,n};c)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7XyPZNs9W2dozLTrzUcfiPJ08fdtMHV3d5Ng6l/y66kydvFrrZE21/wFFmXkl0cq6dmkOyrFq@g5c1YY6ZjqG5jqmZjqWhjqGQMrQyBJEGBsBuUbmxhaGtf//AwA)

Greedy algorithm. Times out on TIO on larger inputs such as `1099511627776`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

Very inefficient. Will time out on TIO for numbers with a large amount of divisors.

```
ÑæʒPQ}€gZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MTDy05NCgisfdS0Jj3q/38jA0tLU0NDMyNzIAAA)

**Explanation**

```
Ñ          # push a list of divisors of the input
 æ         # push the powerset of that list
  ʒPQ}     # filter, keep only the lists whose product is the input
      €g   # get the length of each
        Z  # take the maximum
```

Comment: Your TIO code seems to output 3 instead of 9.

Comment: @Anush: It is a different number than your example (since that one times out due to to many factors). I probably should use a more distinct example.

Comment: `€gZ` is a bit more efficient than `éθg` for the same bytecount.

Comment: @Grimy: True. It won't do much difference as it's the filter that is the big bad guy here, but it doesn't hurt being a bit more efficient :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ŒPP=³ƊƇẈṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//xZJQUD3Cs8aKxofhuojhuYD///8xNQ)

-1 byte thanks to someone

-2 bytes thanks to ErikTheOutgolfer

Comment: While preparing a input for the OEIS superseeker, I created a 11-byte likely golfable Jelly program (that uses a different approach), and am unlikely to post a Jelly answer so I'll pretend I golfed a byte from your solution: `ÆE×8‘½’:2S‘` (it works with the power of the OEIS "formula" section for A003056). Disclaimer: it might be wrong, but it works on the test cases.

Comment: It doesn't seem to terminate with 1099511627776

Comment: @someone doesn't work for 36 but thanks

Comment: @Anush yeah, it's really slow because i code-golfed it, not optimized for efficiency

Comment: I think you can replace `L€` by `Ẉ`. I guess I have a advantage over all other Jelly programmers as I have no idea how to type all of these characters and copy and paste them from the "Atoms" and "Quicks" pages on the wiki like a very odd person and get to automatically read all of the documentation every time.

Comment: @someone I copy paste too, I just suck at reading :D thanks!

Comment: You can remove `ÆD`, it's not like there are more partitions that are going to be created like this, it's just going to take a lot more time (times out for \$x\ge21\$).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer oh true, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 38 bytes

```perl6
{$!=$_;+grep {$!%%$_&&($!/=$_)},1..$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchLCoAgEADQ/ZxigkmKwrSiD@FZpIVG0A9bhXh2c/neY9wxxPNDZlFFT5kivVSbMw8m5DlpxgrKmtRlqCXnpEO0t8Pi2C/zlugB8V0/5MxCiLIdu0mCFEJAL@YBUvw)

Takes the greedy approach to selecting divisors.

Comment: Doesn't terminate with 1099511627776

Comment: @Anush Well, it terminates *eventually*. Generally, the answer is valid if the program's algorithm would work with any input, if it were given as much memory and time as it wanted. Since this is [tag:code-golf], I optimised it for code length, not algorithmic complexity

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES6), 39 bytes

```
f=(n,i=0)=>n%++i?n>i&&f(n,i):1+f(n/i,i)
```

There's probably a few bytes that can be saved here and there. Just uses the greedy algorithm for the factors.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 13 bytes

```
â à f_×¶UÃmÊn
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=4iDgIGZf17ZVw23Kbg&input=Nzg)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
f;?⟨⊇×⟩l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmZiBXA8hJs7Z/NH/Fo672w9MfzV9ZrqSpoPRwV2ftw60T/qNK5fz/H22mY6FjaKRjaKpjaKZjZKJjZK5jbKZjbK5jYqRjYqljZqJjYahjaaBjaADERhY6pmDa3NjCMBYA)

(The naive approach, `{~×≠l}ᶠ⌉`, generates an infinite number of solutions with extra 1s before eliminating them with `≠`, and thus fails to actually terminate. It's not a problem, though, since it's for the same byte count!)

Takes input through the input variable and output through the output variable. The header on TIO contains a copy of most of the code for the sake of showing you what the factor list is, but this works perfectly fine without it. Since `⊇` gives larger sublists first, this predicate essentially does the same thing as most other answers, but without explicitly generating and filtering the complete powerset of the factors, thanks to backtracking.

```
            The output
       l    is the length of
    ⊇       a sublist (the largest satisfying these constraints)
f           of the factors of
            the input
 ; ⟨  ⟩     which
     ×      with its elements multiplied together
  ?         is the input.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
Π=
dz↑⁇(l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//9wCW66UqkdtEx81tmvk/P9vaGRubGEIAA)

Follows the same "algorithm" as seen elsewhere -- filter the divisor powerset for the longest with product equal to the number and return its length.

```
	| helper function
Π=	| is prod(list)==n (implicit)?
	|
	| main function; implicitly takes n
dz	| divisor powerset (in decreasing order of size)
  ↑⁇	| filter by helper function
    (l	| take the first element and take the length (implicitly output)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 77 bytes

```
def f(n:Long)={var(m,c,i)=(n,1,2L);while(i<=m){if(m%i==0){m/=i;c+=1};i+=1};c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY49D4IwFEV3f8VbTNqISjFQ@ejgjpOjcaiV4jO0mEI0hvDbK7Dc4Z6bk9sp2Ujf3l@V6uEs0cLgH5UGTWxWtramYvhIR0ygAqSC2IAFUUnz7xObimAhDB1QE7NGIUI6mL3AXG0EG3NcUo2LzUxiIl3dZXByTv6ul96hrW8UBOjWzQiKLcwLCu8J9Y0leq53fbvcoKvRexYnnkX8cGSehWkaM5ZEnPPkDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Clam](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/Clam), 15 bytes

```
p}_`nq#:;qQ@s~Q
```

TIO link coming soon (when dennis pulls)

Basically a port of @Emigna's 05AB1E solution.

### Explanation

```
                - Implicit Q = first input
p               - Print...
 }              - The last element of...
  _             - Sorted...
   `nq          - Lengths of... (map q => q.len)
           @s   - Items in powerset of
             ~Q - Proper divisors of Q
      #         - Where... (filter)
        ;q      - Product of subset
       :        - Equals...
          Q     - Q
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 54 bytes

```cs
int f(int n,int i=0)=>n%++i<1?1+f(n/i,i):n>i?f(n,i):0;
```

Uses the same approach as @vrugtehagel's and @JoKing's answers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/M69EIU0DRObpgMhMWwNNW7s8VW3tTBtDe0PtNI08/UydTE2rPLtMeyAHxDSw/h9QBFSskaZhaGRubGGoqWn9HwA)

Comment: Assuming I implemented your logic correctly, a 53-byte solution (that I couldn't rid of the "return" keyword): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCsIwFEDRPV@RRUhIi20cFF8TcekcpD8gaVoeyAukqYv47TEOF85y/db6DcscXmF95sDfEWd@9xkjPcIyTNqKFBY@aY5aAht38gNSbmp2NIWM/SwxCUClBgJJR0MHtN2tv7rWKaUQUsh7Iu7gC3Xi2LgC7K9oOmAuVYpR9Pp8uvRSQvkB "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: @someone Thanks, but according to meta, [functions have to be reusable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/84206). Also, I'm don't know if it is acceptable to have declarations outside of the function leave out a trailing semicolon, may make a meta post on that.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 34 bytes

Obviously times out on that massive number, but will eventually time out if given enough time on another machine.

```ruby
->n{(1..n).count{|e|n%e<1?n/=e:p}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cur1rDUE8vT1MvOb80r6S6JrUmTzXVxtA@T9821aqgtvZ/gUJatEq8Xkl@fGasQnlGZk6qQnpqSfF/Q1MzLkMjc2MLQwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
▲mLfo=¹ΠṖḊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9odXNr///ilrJtTGZvPcK5zqDhuZbhuIr///8xMjczODE) A port of [Emigna's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185063).