# Dividing Divisive Divisors

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, number-theory, abstract-algebra

Given a positive integer \$n\$ you can always find a tuple \$(k_1,k_2,...,k_m)\$ of integers \$k_i \geqslant 2\$ such that \$k_1 \cdot k_2 \cdot ... \cdot k_m = n\$ and $$k_1 | k_2 \text{ , } k_2 | k_3 \text{ , } \ldots \text{ , }k_{m-1}|k_m.$$
Here \$a|b\$ means \$b\$ is a multiple of \$a\$, say "a divides b". If \$n>1\$ all entries \$k_i\$ must be at least \$2\$. For \$n=1\$ we have no such factor and therefore we get an empty tuple.

In case you're curious where this comes from: This decomposition is known as *invariant factor decomposition* in number theory and it is used in the [classification of finitely generated
Abelian groups.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Classification)

#### Challenge

Given \$n\$ output *all* such tuples \$(k_1,k_2,...,k_m)\$ for the given \$n\$ exactly once, in whatever order you like. The standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) output formats are allowed.

#### Examples

```
  1: () (empty tuple)
  2: (2)
  3: (3)
  4: (2,2), (4)
  5: (5)
  6: (6)
  7: (7)
  8: (2,2,2), (2,4), (8)
  9: (3,3), (9)
 10: (10)
 11: (11)
 12: (2,6), (12)
108: (2,54), (3,3,12), (3,6,6), (3,36), (6,18), (108)
```

Related: http://oeis.org/A000688, [List all multiplicative partitions of n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104707/list-all-multiplicative-partitions-of-n)

Comment: May we output each tuple in reverse order? (e.g. `12,3,3`)

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, I think as long as it is sorted in ascending or descending order it should be ok!

Comment: Can we limit input to integers >= 2? If not this would invalidate some of the existing answers?

Comment: No, the specs say clearly that any positive integer can be given as input which includes \$n=1\$. If I change it now everyone who actually adheres to the specs would have to change their answer.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>66</s> <s>62</s> 60 bytes

```
f n=[n|n>1]:[k:l:m|k<-[2..n],l:m<-f$div n k,mod(gcd n l)k<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdBDsIgEAXQq/xFF23aTqQrQ6g38ASEGCKiZGDaqHHVuyO7917@w4@ca42Q1cohF@W0ZZ11OdjMdiESN7WZOXYh/SDgqWyhf95Dcx7YKFeLT4IVxe/XG/r9neQLigM6WEWkFodxbDydXf0D)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
Òœ€.œP€`êʒüÖP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8KSjkx81rdE7OjkASCUcXnVq0uE9h6cF/P9vaGABAA)

```
Ò                      # prime factorization of the input
 œ€.œ                  # all partitions
     P                 # product of each sublist
      €`               # flatten
        ê              # sorted uniquified
         ʒ             # filter by:
          üÖ           #  pairwise divisible-by (yields list of 0s or 1s)
            P          #  product (will be 1 iff the list is all 1s)
```

Comment: Nice way of using `Òœ€.œP` to get the sublists. I indeed had trouble finding something shorter as well.. If only there was a builtin similar to `Åœ` but for product instead of sum. ;)

Comment: Fails for n=1 (see comments on question)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
ÆfŒ!Œb€ẎP€€QḍƝẠ$Ƈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW9rRSYpHJyU9alrzcFdfAJACosCHO3qPzX24a4HKsfb/h9uPTnq4c8b//4YGFgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/),  <s>73</s>  70 bytes

Prints the tuples in descending order \$(k_m,k_{m-1},...,k_1)\$.

```javascript
f=(n,d=2,a=[])=>n>1?d>n||f(n,d+1,a,d%a[0]||f(n/d,d,[d,...a])):print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2/DoIwHIR3nuK3GGg8K8V/KGmdXH2BpkNDQ8ShEiQs4rPXCtN9@S6Xe9rRvuu@7YbNWIbQyMzDyQJWasOk8kpcnfLT1Pz9WsDCrazOzWy2Dg7agXNuDWOXrm/9kFkWKi1QYIc9DjjihBJniBxCQBQRSpPw5tXfbP3IPElFn4RoGad3kpTSmjyroowncy5lxC8LPw)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (             // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,              //   n   = input
  d = 2,          //   d   = current divisor
  a = []          //   a[] = list of divisors
) =>              //
  n > 1 ?         // if n is greater than 1:
    d > n ||      //   unless d is greater than n,
    f(            //   do a recursive call with:
      n,          //     -> n unchanged
      d + 1,      //     -> d + 1
      a,          //     -> a[] unchanged
      d % a[0] || //     unless the previous divisor does not divide the current one,
      f(          //     do another recursive call with:
        n / d,    //       -> n / d
        d,        //       -> d unchanged
        [d, ...a] //       -> d preprended to a[]
      )           //     end of inner recursive call
    )             //   end of outer recursive call
  :               // else:
    print(a)      //   this is a valid list of divisors: print it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>17</s> <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ñ¦IиæʒPQ}êʒüÖP
```

Very slow for larger test cases.

-1 byte thanks to *@Grimy*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9vc2FiaWX//8ORwqZJ0LjDpsqSUFF9w6rKksO8w5ZQ//80)

**Explanation:**

```python
Ñ               # Get all divisors of the (implicit) input-integer
 ¦              # Remove the first value (the 1)
  Iи            # Repeat this list (flattened) the input amount of times
                #  i.e. with input 4 we now have [2,4,2,4,2,4,2,4]
    æ           # Take the powerset of this list
     ʒ  }       # Filter it by:
      PQ        #  Where the product is equal to the (implicit) input
         ê      # Then sort and uniquify the filtered lists
          ʒ     # And filter it further by:
           ü    #  Loop over each overlapping pair of values
            Ö   #   And check if the first value is divisible by the second value
             P  #  Check if this is truthy for all pairs
              
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: @Grimy Thanks. And good call on the divisors. It's still very slow for \$n=8\$, but all bits help, and if it doesn't cost any additional bytes to improve the performance, then why not use it. :)

Comment: [13 and faster](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191529/dividing-divisive-divisors/191531#191531). Feels like it can be shorter still.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>78</s> <s>76</s> ... <s>61</s> 51 bytes

```
Do[i∣##&&##~#0~i,{i,2,-#/-##2/. 1:>Print@{##2}}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yU/OvNRx2JlZTU1ZeU6ZYO6TJ3qTB0jHV1lfV1lZSN9PQVDK7uAosy8EodqIL@2Nlbtf5qDlmtyRn5dcHJiXl01l6EOl5EOl7EOl4kOl6kOl5kOl7kOl4UOl6UOl6EBEAPlDY1AbAuuWn39wNLM1JL/AA)

Recursive search tree.

Prints the list of decompositions.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 115 bytes

```
f=(n,a=[],i=1)=>{for(;i++<n;)n%i||(a=a.concat(f(n/i).filter(e=>!(e[0]%i)).map(e=>[i].concat(e))));return n>1?a:[a]}
```

I will write an explanation later

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>22</s> 19 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ÆâÃcÅà â f@¶XcXäv)×
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=xuLDY8XgIOIgZkC2WGNY5HYp1w&footer=8SBxUg&input=NA)

```
ÆâÃcÅà â f@¶XcXäv)×     :Implicit input of integer U
Æ                       :Map the range [0,U)
 â                      :  Divisors of U
  Ã                     :End map
   c                    :Flatten after
    Å                   :  Slicing the first element off each
     à                  :Combinations
       â                :Deduplicate
         f              :Filter by
          @             :Passing each X through the following function
           ¶            :  Test U for equality with
            Xc          :  Concatenate to X
              Xä        :    Consecutive pairs of X
                v       :    Reduced by testing divisibility
                 )      :  End concat
                  ×     :  Reduce by multiplication
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>18</s></sup> 15 bytes

```
fΛ¦ufo=¹ΠṖmΠtṖp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@3c7EPLStPybQ/tPLfg4c5puecWlACpgv///1sAAA)

Similar to Grimmy's 05AB1E answer.

-3 bytes from Zgarb.

Comment: `oΛIẊ¦` can be just `Λ¦`. `ΛV` can take binary functions and check the condition on adjacent pairs.

Comment: Clean. I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
ḊœċRẎḍƝẠ×P=¥ʋƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//4biKxZPEi1Lhuo7huI3GneG6oMOXUD3CpcqLxof/MTDDh@KCrMWS4bmY4oKsWf8)

### How it works

```
ḊœċRẎḍƝẠ×P=¥ʋƇ - Main link. Takes n on the left
Ḋ              - Dequeue; Yield [2, 3, ..., n]
   R           - Range, Yield [1, 2, ..., n]
 œċ            - For each integer, 1 ≤ i ≤ n, yield combinations with
                  replacement of length i from the dequeued range
    Ẏ          - Tighten into a single list of lists
            ʋƇ - Keep those for which the following is true:
        ×  ¥   -   Both of the following are true:
      Ɲ        -     Over overlapping pairs:
     ḍ         -       Is the left divisible by the right?
       Ạ       -     Is all true?
        ×      -   And:
         P     -     The product
          =    -     Equals n?
```