# Output "Fit" numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

## "Fit Numbers"

Sam has a "brilliant" idea for compression! Can you help?

---

Here is a rundown of Sam's compression scheme. First take in a base 10 representation of any natural number strictly smaller than 2^16, and write it as a binary string without any leading zeros.

```
1 -> 1
9 -> 1001
15 ->1111
13 ->1101
16 -> 10000
17 -> 10001
65535 -> 111111111111111
```

Now replace any group of one or more zeros with a single zero. This is because the number has gotten leaner. Your binary string now will look like this.

```
1 -> 1 -> 1
9 -> 1001 -> 101
15 ->1111 -> 1111
13 ->1101 -> 1101
16 -> 10000 -> 10
17 -> 10001 -> 101
65535 -> 111111111111111 -> 111111111111111
```

Now you convert the binary string back to a base 10 representation, and output it in any acceptable format. Here are your test cases. The first integer represents an input, and the last integer represents an output. Note that some numbers do not change, and thus can be called "fit"

```
1 -> 1 -> 1 -> 1
9 -> 1001 -> 101 -> 5
15 ->1111 -> 1111 -> 15
13 ->1101 -> 1101 -> 13
16 -> 10000 -> 10 -> 2
17 -> 10001 -> 101 -> 5
65535 -> 1111111111111111 -> 1111111111111111 -> 65535
65000 -> 1111110111101000 -> 11111101111010 -> 16250
```

---

You may use any language, but please note that Sam hates standard loopholes. This is code golf so the code can be as short as possible to make room for the "compressed" numbers".

---

Note:This is NOT an acceptable compression scheme. Using this will promptly get you fired.

---

Citation-Needed: I do not take credit for this concept. This comes from @Conor O' Brien's blog [here](http://cergos.blogspot.com/2016/02/fitbits.html) see this OEIS of fit numbers. https://oeis.org/A090078

Comment: From @Conor's comic blog: [link](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mQr2LHIF6fM/Vrae4WGmMGI/AAAAAAAAA8s/7hpffR5FbUg/s320/fitbit.png)

Comment: [OEIS A090078](https://oeis.org/A090078) might come in handy.

Comment: It is I who wrote the comic. <s>I also expect a 35% rep royalty</s> ;)

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain the issue?

Comment: Why is 16 equal to 8? Shouldn't 16 be `10000`?

Comment: @eithedog 16 goes to 10000, and then you crunch the consecutive zeros down. So 16 goes to 10000 10 goes to 2 and 8 goes to 1000 goes to 10 goes to two

Comment: But you wrote `16 -> 1000 -> 10 -> 2`. Shouldn't it be `16 -> 10000 -> 10 -> 2`?

Comment: @Dennis whoops fixing now!

Comment: @eithedog my bad

Comment: Do we need to convert back to decimal?

Comment: The first code block still has 16 and 17 wrong.

Comment: @LeakyNun yes you do

Comment: @immibis fixing now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
b00¬:C
```

**Explanation**

```
b        # convert input to binary
 00¬:    # replace 00 with 0 while possible
     C   # convert to int
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=YjAwwqw6Qw&input=NjUwMDA)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan)

Comment: You can replace `„00'0` by `00¬` :).

Comment: @Adnan Nice! Didn't think of that.

Comment: I don't even know why I explicitly pushed them as strings...

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit counterintuitive, but it works :).

Comment: This is looking like it will win :D, i'll give it a bit more time before accepting so that more people can participate.

Answer (score 13):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 27

```
dc -e2o?p|tr -s 0|dc -e2i?p
```

Input read from STDIN.

Comment: Nice! I have never used `dc` :)

Comment: The [dc man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html) reads a lot like the docs for some golfing languages.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), 41 bytes

```
n=>+`0b${n.toString(2).replace(/0+/g,0)}`
```

Answer (score 7):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 20 bytes

```
p
d
# S
,1
*
\dbi
 2
```

[Try it online!](http://jellyfish.tryitonline.net/#code=cApkCiMgUwosMQoqClxkYmkKIDI&input=MTc)

### Explanation

- `i` is input.
- `b` converts it to binary (list of digits)
- `\d` with arguments `2` and the digit list applies `d` (binary digits to number) to every length-2 substring of the digit list.
- `*` takes signum of the results: 00 goes to 0, everything else to 1.
- `,1` tacks a 1 to the end, so the last digit is not lost.
- `# S` selects from `bi` those digits which have a 1 on the list computed above: those that are not the left halves of 00.
- `d` converts back to number, and `p` prints the result.

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, 36 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and f(n/2)<<(n%4>0)|n%2
```

A direct recursive implementation with no base conversion built-ins or string operations. Less golfed:

```python
f=lambda n:n and[f(n/2),n%2+2*f(n/2)][n%4>0]
```

When `n` is a multiple of 4, it ends in two 0's in binary, so we cut one by floor-dividing by 2. Otherwise, we split `n` into `(n%2) + 2*(n/2)`, leave the last binary digit `n%2` alone, and recurse on the other digits `n/2`.

Comment: Isn't `n%2` redundant?

Comment: @xsot Not sure what you mean. Doing `|n` gives wrong results.

Comment: I mean you can replace the whole of `(n%4>0)|n%2` with `(n%4>0)`.

Comment: @xsot The precedence goes as `(f(n/2)<<(n%4>0)) | n%2`.

Comment: Ah, my bad then. I thought shifting has the lowest precedence.

Answer (score 5):

## Bash (sed + bc), <s>60</s> <s>55</s> 43 bytes

```
echo $[2#`bc<<<obase=2\;$1|sed s/00\*/0/g`]
```

edit:

1. changed `sed -E 's/0+` to `sed 's/00*` and changed echo and pipe used to pass the value to bc with `<<<`.
2. Brilliant suggestion by @Digital Trauma!

example:

```
$ bash script.sh 65000
16250
$ bash script.sh 15
15
$ bash script.sh 9
5
```

Comment: sed + bc was my first thought too. `echo "obase=2;$1"|bc|sed 's/00*/0/g;s/^/ibase=2;/'|bc` is 2 bytes shorter

Comment: Use pipes and escapes to your advantage: `echo $[2#\`bc<<<obase=2\;$1|sed s/00\*/0/g\`]`.  But `dc` and `tr` [make it way shorter](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90086/11259).

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: Thanks, that's great! @Riley: nice idea, it would be a bit shorter like that: `bc<<<"obase=2;$1"|sed 's/00*/0/g;s/^/ibase=2;/'|bc`

Comment: if you use `tr -s 0` instead of sed you can get down to 36 bytes

Comment: @Riley: True, but Digital Trauma already uses it in the other bash answer so I prefer not to use it :)

Comment: Good call, I didn't see his.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>55</s>, 50 bytes.

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Sp3000.

Pretty straightforward solution.

```
import re
f=lambda x:eval(re.sub('0+','0',bin(x)))
```

Comment: Can you keep the `0b` and just `eval` instead?

Comment: @Sp3000 Certainly can! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Anonymous lambdas are allowed; you can shrink this to 48 bytes by using `lambda x:eval(re.sub('0+','0',bin(x))) <insert newline here> import re`

Answer (score 4):

## MATL, <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
BFFOZtXB
```

This version works only in MATLAB since `strrep` in MATLAB can handle logical inputs. Here is a version that will work in Octave (9 bytes) (and thus the online interpreter) which explicitly casts the logical inputs to type `double`.

[**Try it online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Qm9GRk9adFhC&input=OQ)

**Explanation**

```
    % Implicitly grab input
B   % Convert decimal to binary
FF  % Create the array [0 0]
O   % Number literal
Zt  % Replaces all [0 0] with [0] (will replace any number of 0's with 0)
XB  % Convert binary to decimal
    % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>31</s>  27 bytes

```perl6
{:2(.base(2).subst(:g,/0+/,0))}
{:2(.base(2)~~{S:g/0+/0/})}
```

### Explanation:

```perl6
-> $_ {
  # convert from base 2
  :2(

    # convert to base 2
    $_.base(2)

    # substitute
    .subst(
      :global,
      / 0+ /,  # all substrings made of 0s
      '0'      # with one 0
    )
  )
}
```

### Example:

```perl6
my &fit-compress = {:2(.base(2)~~{S:g/0+/0/})}
say fit-compress 1;     # 1
say fit-compress 9;     # 5
say fit-compress 15;    # 15
say fit-compress 13;    # 13
say fit-compress 16;    # 2
say fit-compress 17;    # 5
say fit-compress 65535; # 65535
say fit-compress 65000; # 16250

# number created with ｢:2( [~] <0 1>.roll: 256 )｣
say fit-compress 80794946326210692074631955353531749442835289622757526957697718534769445507500
# 4240335298301026395935723255481812004519990428936918
```

Answer (score 3):

### Actually, 14 bytes

```
├`'0;;+(Æ`Y2@¿
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4pScYCcwOzsrKMOGYFkyQMK_&input=NjUwMDA)

Explanation:

```
├`'0;;+(Æ`Y2@¿
├               bin(input) (automatically discards leading zeroes)
 `'0;;+(Æ`Y     call this function until the output stops changing:
  '0;;+           push "0", "00"
       (Æ         replace "00" with "0" in binary string
           2@¿  convert from binary to decimal
```

Comment: Then post a competing version!

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>35</s> 31 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @Doorknob

```
->n{eval ("0b%b"%n).squeeze ?0}
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/CnnQ/2

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript (ES6), 40 bytes

```
n=>'0b'+n.toString(2).replace(/0+/g,0)-0
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is a snippet. Unless the challenge description states otherwise, the solutions are expected to be either full programs or functions.

Comment: What require to be "full program" in Javascript if I don't want to use function? Please advise.

Comment: For example with Node.js: `console.log(+('0b'+parseInt(process.argv[1]).toString(2).replace(/0+/g,0)))`.

Comment: Off topic. Your code block [has the same problem](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/90080/3) as @Master_ex. Is it because some popular shell config scripts polluting the terminal? Or SE's fault?

Comment: The site engine inserts U+200C (zero width non-joiner) and U+200B (zero width space) character pairs in the code part of comments.

Comment: The shortest fix would be to prepend `N=>` which would make it a valid function submission.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <strike>53</strike> 51 Bytes

```
<?=bindec(preg_replace("/0+/",0,decbin($argv[1])));
```

Takes an argument from the console.

### Thanks to:

@manatwork replace "0" with 0

Comment: Mostly `"0"` and `0` are handled in the same way.

Comment: @manatwork Thanks. That was a pretty obvious one I should have seen myself.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 7 bytes

**6 bytes thanks to Zgarb for [his algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90083/48934).**

```
BŒgµL*x@Ḣµ€FḄ
BŒgḄBFḄ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=QsWSZ-G4hEJG4biE&input=&args=NjUwMDA)

Answer (score 2):

### C#, <s>112</s> 91 bytes

```
int x(int x)=>Convert.ToInt32(Rege‌​x.Replace(Convert.ToS‌​tring(x,2),"0+","0"),2);
```

-8 bytes thanks to TuukkaX

Comment: `int f(int x){var a=Regex.Replace(Convert.ToString(x,2),"0+","0");return Convert.ToInt32(a,2);}` - 94 bytes using regex. I've seen a lot of C# solutions not include `System.Text.RegularExpressions` so maybe it's allowed here too...?

Comment: `int f(int x){return Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(Convert.ToString(x,2),"0+","0"),2);}` 86 bytes.

Comment: i dont know how you are counting bytes, i use this https://mothereff.in/byte-counter

Comment: I use that page too, but it wouldn't work, so I used a different page. You should also mention the required C# version.

Comment: mothereff.in/byte-counter calculates 79 bytes for your current solution. I had to type the solution by hand, otherwise it would give me 91.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 38 + 1 (`-p`) = 39 bytes

```pl
$_=oct"0b".sprintf("%b",$_)=~s/0+/0/gr
```

Needs `-p` flag to run (I added `-l` flag to make it more readable, but it's not needed otherwise) :

```
perl -plE '$_=oct"0b".sprintf("%b",$_)=~s/0+/0/gr' <<< "1
9
15
13
16
17
65535
65000"
```

Note much to say about the code : it converts the number into binary (`sprintf"%b"`), then replaces blocs of zeros by just one zero, and converts the result into decimal (`oct"0b".`).

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 75

```java
int f(Integer x){return x.valueOf(x.toString(x,2).replaceAll("0+","0"),2);}
```

Test program:

```java
public class Fit {
    int f(Integer x){return x.valueOf(x.toString(x,2).replaceAll("0+","0"),2);}

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final Fit x = new Fit();
        System.out.println(x.f(65000));
    }
}
```

Comment: Java 8 convert to lamda x->blah; for fewer bytes

Comment: int f(Integer x){return x.parseInt(x.toString(x,2).replaceAll("0+","0"));} for a couple fewer bytes

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala That's wrong, it needs to use base 2. As for the lambda, I feel that it's incomplete without the type specification.

Comment: oh ok, the other java answer uses the same technique

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90085/46918

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), <s>54</s> 43 bytes

```
n->fold((a,b)->a+if(b,a+1,a%2,a),binary(n))
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 37 bytes

```
f(x){return x?f(x/2)<<!!(x%4)|x&1:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Reference Implementation in [S.I.L.O.S](https://esolangs.org/wiki/S.I.L.O.S) "only" 417 bytes

Golfed

```
readIO :
i + 1
I = i
z = 1 
n = 32
b = n
z = 1
n = b
lbla
n - 1
GOSUB p
j = i
j - p
if j b
if z c
z = 1
GOTO e
lblc
b - 1
if n a
GOTO f
lblb
z = 0
A = a
A + 1000
set A 1
i - p
lble
a + 1
if n a
lblf
q = 1000
e = q
e + b
i = 0
lbl>
d = q
d - e
if d ?
n = b
n - i
GOSUB p
g = get q
g * p
o + g
i + 1
q + 1
GOTO >
lbl?
o / 2
printInt o
GOTO z
funcp
p = 1
Z = n
lblQ
if Z C
GOTO D
lblC
Z - 1
p * 2
GOTO Q
lblD
return
lblz
```

Here is the reference implementation fully ungolfed. As a bonus feature it outputs the steps needed to come to an answer.

```
/**
*Reference Implementation in the high quality S.I.L.O.S language.
*/
readIO Enter a number to "compress"
//some declarations
i + 1
I = i
z = 1 
//the above is a flag which shows whether or not a zero was last outputted
n = 32
b = n
//maximum number of input bits
printLine Original Binary



lblbinLoop
n - 1
GOSUB pow
j = I
j - p
if j printOne
if z ENDLOOP
print 0
GOTO ENDLOOP
lblprintOne
z = 0
print 1
I - p
lblENDLOOP
if n binLoop




printLine  
printLine Binary "Compressed"


z = 1
n = b


lbltopA
n - 1
GOSUB pow
j = i
j - p
if j printAOne
if z DontPrint
z = 1
print 0
GOTO ENDLOOPA
lblDontPrint
b - 1
if n topA
GOTO endOfBin
lblprintAOne
z = 0
print 1
A = a
A + 1000
set A 1
i - p
lblENDLOOPA
a + 1
if n topA

lblendOfBin

printLine  
printLine -----------
printLine Base 10 Output
print Out Bits:
printInt b

q = 1000
e = q
e + b
i = 0
lblOutputDec
d = q
d - e
if d DONE
n = b
n - i
GOSUB pow
g = get q
g * p
o + g
i + 1
q + 1
GOTO OutputDec
lblDONE
printLine
printLine ---------
o / 2
printInt o

GOTO funcs
//function declarations must be wrapped in gotoes to avoid the interpreter from complaining (breaking)

/**
*This will store the nth power of two in the "p" variable
*/
funcpow
p = 1
Z = n
lbltop
if Z continue
GOTO end
lblcontinue
Z - 1
p * 2
GOTO top
lblend
return

lblfuncs
```

By request the transpilation has been deleted. Feel free to view the edit history to recover it, otherwise go to [this repo](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S) for an interpreter.

Sample output for 65000

```
Enter a number to "compress"
65000
Original Binary
1111110111101000 
Binary "Compressed"
11111101111010 
-----------
Base 10 Output
Out Bits:14
---------
16250
```

Comment: Reference implementations should be in the challenge body, not as answers, since they are ungolfed and thus not serious contenders.

Comment: Ok, I'll golf it.

Comment: I didn't want to bloat up the challenge body with this @Mego

Comment: @TimmyD one second I'm golfing it down now

Comment: @Mego I have golfed it now

Comment: @Dopapp it is a trivial transpilation down to Java

Comment: @Dopapp it has been removed

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain the issue with the post so I can correct it or remove it as needed?

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, 69 bytes

```
[convert]::ToInt32(([convert]::ToString($args[0],2)-replace'0+',0),2)
```

(*[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)A shorter way to convert to/from binary in PowerShell*)

Takes input `$args[0]`, uses the .NET built-in `[convert]::ToString(int,base)` to convert the input integer into a binary base string. That's filtered through the `-replace` to strip out any runs of one-or-more-zeros to just `0`. That resultant string is sent back through the other direction via `[convert]::ToInt32(string,base)` to turn the binary back into an integer. That integer is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

#### Test Cases

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> 1,9,15,13,16,17,65535,65000|%{"$_ -> " +(.\output-fit-number.ps1 $_)}
1 -> 1
9 -> 5
15 -> 15
13 -> 13
16 -> 2
17 -> 5
65535 -> 65535
65000 -> 16250
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>152</s> <s>143</s> 138 bytes

```
interface C{static void main(String[]b){Integer i=0;System.out.print(i.parseInt(i.toString(i.parseInt(b[0]),2).replaceAll("0+","0"),2));}}
```

- 9 bytes less thanks to @RohanJhunjhunwala. I prefer to keep it as a fully functioning program with main and the like. However, of course it can be golfed more otherwise.
- 5 bytes less thanks to @LeakyNun's suggestions.

Comment: class A{public static void main(String[] a){Integer i;System.out.print(i.parseInt(i.toBinaryString(i.parseInt(a[0])).replaceAll("0+","0"),2));}} for 8 bytes of saving

Comment: wrap it in a lambda expression for even more saving and remove class definitions, and your set.

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala:Ah! The `Integer i;` part is simple and fantastic!

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala: Hm.. However it means that Integer should get imported and that adds more bytes to the total program...

Comment: interface Z{static void main(String[]b){Integer i=0;System.out.print(i.parseInt(i.toBinaryString(i.parseInt(b[0])).replaceAll("0+","0"),2));}} works like a charm without imports and golfs off 10 bytes

Comment: It works, but may produce a warning (as opposed to an error) on most sane IDE's. The thing is, you can always call static methods from a non static context, but you can never call a non-static method from a static context. While using this technique is strongly strongly discouraged in production code, it is legal java.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java Is a good read to get more familiar with the lesser known (dare I say shadier) "features" of the java language.

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala: Yeah, I got a bit confused with my IDE warnings for a moment there. Thanks for the link with the java golf tips. I have spotted it but haven't read it yet. I sure plan to read it though :)

Comment: @Master_ex Integer is part of java.lang and so doesn't need to be imported

Comment: `String[] b` -> `String[]b`

Comment: You can use `i.toString(123,2)` instead of `i.toBinaryString(123)`

Comment: You don't need to convert back to decimal?

Comment: @yitzih: Yeah, I got a bit confused at first because of my IDE warnings.
@LeakyNun: It does indeed convert back to decimal. This, the outer `parseInt`, is for.

Comment: interface C{Integer i;static void main(String[]b){System.out.print(i.parseInt(i.toString(i.parseInt(b[0]),2).replaceAll("0+","0"),2));}}

Comment: for two bytes off

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 12

```
i:.BQ"0+"\02
```

[Online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=i%3A.BQ%220%2B%22%5C02&input=65000&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A9%0A15%0A13%0A16%0A17%0A65535%0A65000&debug=0)

```
  .BQ            # Convert input from base 10 to base 2
 :   "0+"\0      # Replace multiple zeroes with single zero
i          2     # Convert back from base 2 to base 10
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 30 bytes

```
.+
$*1;
+`(1+)\1
$1;
1;
1
;+
0
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKJCoxOworYCgxKylcMQokMTsKMTsKMQo7Kwow&input=NjUwMDA)

And here I thought Retina would be amongst the first answers...

Comment: @randomra I'm asking the question OP for clarification

Comment: Is Retina  capable of binary to  decimal conversion or binary to unary conversion? I'll except either one so as to not exclude Retina

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala: [Yes, it is](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/Tutorial:-Unary-arithmetic#binary-to-unary)

Comment: Is it possible to make this convert to unary or decimal? Ideally I would like to see decimal, but I will accept either.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 19 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
{2⊥⍵/⍨~0 0⍷⍵}2∘⊥⍣¯1
```

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%7B2%u22A5%u2375/%u2368%7E0%200%u2377%u2375%7D2%u2218%u22A5%u2363%AF1%20%u22C4%20f%A81%209%2015%2013%2016%2017%2065535%2065000&run)

**This function is really an "atop" of two functions, the first function is:**

`2∘⊥⍣¯1` the *inverse* of binary-*to*-decimal conversion, i.e. binary-*from*-decimal conversion
 *two* `2` *is bound* `∘` to *-to-decimal* `⊥`
 *repeat* the operation `⍣` *negative one* time `¯1` (i.e. once, but inverted)

**In the second function, the above's binary result is represented by** `⍵`**:**

`{2⊥⍵/⍨~0 0⍷⍵}`
 `0 0⍷⍵` Boolean for where {0, 0} begins in ⍵
 `~` Boolean negation, so now we have ᴛʀᴜᴇ everywhere but at non-first zeros in zero-runs
 `⍵/⍨` use that to filter ⍵, so this removes our unwanted zeros
 `2⊥` convert binary-to-decimal

Answer (score 1):

## TSQL, 143 bytes

Not using build ins to convert from and to binary.

Golfed:

```
DECLARE @i INT=65000

,@ CHAR(99)=''WHILE @i>0SELECT @=REPLACE(LEFT(@i%2,1)+@,'00',0),@i/=2WHILE @>''SELECT @i+=LEFT(@,1)*POWER(2,LEN(@)-1),@=STUFF(@,1,1,'')PRINT @i
```

Ungolfed:

```
DECLARE @i INT=65000

,@ CHAR(99)=''
WHILE @i>0
  SELECT @=REPLACE(LEFT(@i%2,1)+@,'00',0),@i/=2

WHILE @>''
  SELECT @i+=LEFT(@,1)*POWER(2,LEN(@)-1),@=STUFF(@,1,1,'')

PRINT @i
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/525494/output-fit-numbers)**

Comment: +1 for not using built ins. My S.I.L.O.S answer (reference implementation)  does the same, but it got downvoted as people didn't think it was a serious competitor.  Is the new line significant?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala the new line is not significant. I am counting the characters of the code after the input variable has been defined and assigned a value.

Comment: ok amkes sense -

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala I think it is cool that you use an unconversial language to solve Codegolf questions. It does seem you have unnecessary code to add extra information - probably only in your ungolfed version though. You should always try to provide the shortest code possible, cutting corners and abusing language querks(within the scope of the question). If possible you should provide a fiddle, so muggles me can test it

Comment: The ungolfed version contains unnecessary code, but the golfed version contains no additional code. I can transpiler it into java if you want me to test it.

Comment: no need for a java version, I find the syntax of S.I.L.O.S fascinating and primitive - reminds me of my old TI99/4A. It will never be able to compete. But that should not prevent it from participating IMHO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44099/discussion-between-rohan-jhunjhunwala-and-t-clausen-dk).

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 16

```
q~2b1+0a%0a*);2b
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~2b1%2B0a%250a*)%3B2b&input=65000)

It's quite long due to lack of regex.

**Explanation:**

```
q~     read and evaluate the input number
2b     convert to base 2 (array of 1s and 0s)
1+     append a 1 to deal with trailing zeros
0a%    split by [0], dropping empty pieces; only chunks of 1s are left
0a*    join by [0]
);     discard the 1 we appended before
2b     convert back from base 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 23 bytes

```
ri2be`{_:g:>{:g}&}%e~2b
```

[**Try it online!**](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmkyYmVge186Zzo-ezpnfSZ9JWV-MmI&input=MTc)

#### Explanation

```
ri          e# Read input as an integer
2b          e# Convert to binary
e`          e# Run-length encoding. Gives a nested (2D) array with run-lengths 
            e# and binary digits
{           e# This block is mapped over the outer array, i.e. is applied to
            e# each inner array
   _        e#   Duplicate the inner array
  :g        e#   Signum of each element of inner array
  :>        e#   This gives true if second element (digit) is false and first
            e#   element (run-length) is not zero. If so, we need to set that
            e#   run-length to 1
  {:g}&     e#   If that's the case, apply signum to original copy of inner
            e#   array, to make run-length 1
}%          e# End block which is mapped over the outer array
e~          e# Run-length decoding
2b          e# Convert from binary. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 64 bytes

```
i->{return i.parseInt(i.toString(i,2).replaceAll("0+","0"),2);};
```

## Test Program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function<Integer, Integer> function = i -> {
        return i.parseInt(i.toString(i, 2).replaceAll("0+", "0"), 2);
    };

    System.out.println(function.apply(1)); // 1
    System.out.println(function.apply(9)); // 5
    System.out.println(function.apply(15)); // 15
    System.out.println(function.apply(13)); // 13
    System.out.println(function.apply(16)); // 2
    System.out.println(function.apply(17)); // 5
    System.out.println(function.apply(65535)); // 65535
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Ruby, <strike>37</strike> 35 bytes

Saved two bytes thanks to manatwork.

```
->a{a.to_s(2).gsub(/0+/,?0).to_i 2}
```

The naive approach. (:

Comment: Regarding `"0"`, see the 2nd point in [sepp2k](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30/sepp2k)'s [tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/377). Regarding `.to_i(2)`, where there is no ambiguity on where a parameter belongs, the parentheses are optional.

Answer (score 1):

## [S.I.L.O.S](http://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 120 bytes

```
readIO 
p = 1
lbla
m = i
m % 2
M = m
M - 1
M * F
M + 2
p * M
F = 1
F - m
A = p
A * m
r + A
i / 2
if i a
r / 2
printInt r
```

[Try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=cmVhZElPIApwID0gMQpsYmxhCm0gPSBpCm0gJSAyCk0gPSBtCk0gLSAxCk0gKiBGCk0gKyAyCnAgKiBNCkYgPSAxCkYgLSBtCkEgPSBwCkEgKiBtCnIgKyBBCmkgLyAyCmlmIGkgYQpyIC8gMgpwcmludEludCBy&input=&args=NjUwMDA)

This is basically a state machine.

- `p` for the current power
- `m` for the result of the modulo by 2
- `M` for the multiplier (to the power); if we are stuck at zeroes, the multiplier would be 1
- `F` for the flag, to denote whether the zero is the first zero in the run.
- `r` for the result, which is printed at the end.

The conversion between `m`, `M` and `F` is as follows:

- `m=0, F=0 -> F=1, M=2` (first zero, multiply by 2 anyway)
- `m=0, F=1 -> F=1, M=1` (not the first zero, multiply by 1)
- `m=1, F=0 -> F=0, M=2` (it is a one, multiply by 2, reset flag)
- `m=1, F=1 -> F=0, M=2` (it is a one, multiply by 2, reset flag)

Essentially we come up with the following formula:

- `M=((m-1)*F)+2`
- `F=1-m`

Comment: Wow, that golf. So much shorter than the reference

Answer (score 1):

## [Oasis](http://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 25 bytes (non-competing)

```
n2÷an»»n»4÷xx-p>*nn2÷x-+0
```

[Try it online!](http://oasis.tryitonline.net/#code=bjLDt2FuwrvCu27CuzTDt3h4LXA-Km5uMsO3eC0rMA&input=&args=NjUwMDA)

I have not failed my master. \o/

There are many missing features which must be built. For example, there is no conditionals, so the formula I am using would be `f(n/2)*[1+(n%4>0)] + n%2`.

Actually, there is no modulo either, so `n%2` is implemented as `n-(n/2*2)` where `/` is integer division.

I did not mention `n%4`, because there is no `>` either. The `>` in the code means `+1`. So, `n%4>0` is built from `is_prime(((n+2)%4)+2)` where the modulo is generated as above.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>11 10</s></sup> 9 bytes

```
ḋṁS↑o→Σgḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GO7oc7G4MftU3Mf9Q26dzidKDA////zUwNDAwA)

-1 byte from [H.PWiz.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55728012#55728012)

-1 byte from Jo King.

## Alternative 9-byter

```
ḋṁ?uIΛ¬gḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GO7oc7G@1LPc/NPrQmHcj7//@/mamBgQEA)

### Explanation

```
ḋṁ?uIΛ≠1gḋ
         ḋ get binary digits
        g  group equal runs of digits
 ṁ         map each group to the following, and concatenate:
  ?  Λ≠1   if all elements are not equal to 1
   u       uniquify the group
    I      else leave it as is
ḋ          convert back to base-10
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 29 bytes

Based on [my Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90075/11261).

```ruby
:%&"0b%b"|~:squeeze&?0|-:eval
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWe61U1ZQMklSTlGrqrIoLS1NTq1LV7A1qdK1SyxJzIGpWFSi4RZuZGhgYxEIEFiyA0AA)