# Appending String Lengths

Tags: code-golf, string

#### Challenge:

Given a string `s` on the characters `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`, `0`-`9`, append the length of `s` to itself, counting the additional character(s) in the length as part of the total length of `s`.

#### Input:

Just a string of arbitrary length (can be empty).

#### Output:

The same string, but with its length appended to the end.  The characters that represent the length should also be counted as part of the length.  In cases where there are multiple valid lengths to append, choose the smallest one possible (see test cases for examples).

#### Test Cases:

```
INPUT     -> OUTPUT       // Comment
aaa       -> aaa4
          -> 1            // Empty string
aaaaaaaa  -> aaaaaaaa9    // aaaaaaaa10 would also normally be valid, but violates using the smallest number rule mentioned above
aaaaaaaaa -> aaaaaaaaa11
a1        -> a13          // Input can contain numbers at the end of the string, you do not have to handle the fact that it looks like 13 rather than 3.

Longer test case(s):

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa -> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa101
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa -> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa102
```

#### Rules:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.  Standard loopholes are forbidden.  Submissions may be an entire program or a function, and you may either print the result to stdout or return it as a variable from a function.

Comment: What characters can appear in the input?

Comment: @MartinEnder Alphanumerical characters only, 0-9 and A-Z/a-z.  So yes, you can have strings with numbers at the end.  I'll add a test case for one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth - 7 bytes

```
+Qfql+Q
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BQfql%2BQ&input=%22Aaaaaaaa%22&debug=0).

Answer (score 19):

### JavaScript (ES6), 32 bytes

```js
f=(s,n=0)=>(s+n)[n]?f(s,n+1):s+n
```

#### How it works

```js
f = (s, n = 0) =>   // given a string 's' and starting with n = 0:
  (s + n)[n] ?      // if the Nth character of (s + n) exists:
    f(s, n + 1)     //   try again with n + 1
  :                 // else
    s + n           //   return s + n
```

Starting with `N=0`, we test the Nth character (0-based) of the string made of the concatenation of the original input string and the decimal representation of `N`. We increment `N` until this character doesn't exist anymore.

Example:

```
N =  0 : abcdefghi0
         ^
N =  1 : abcdefghi1
          ^
N =  2 : abcdefghi2
           ^
...
N =  8 : abcdefghi8
                 ^
N =  9 : abcdefghi9
                  ^
N = 10 : abcdefghi10
                   ^
N = 11 : abcdefghi11    -> success
                    ^
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(s,n=0)=>(s+n)[n]?f(s,n+1):s+n

console.log(f("aaa"));       // -> aaa4
console.log(f(""));          // -> 1
console.log(f("aaaaaaaa"));  // -> aaaaaaaa9
console.log(f("aaaaaaaaa")); // -> aaaaaaaaa11
console.log(f("a1"));        // -> a13
```

Comment: Wow, JS is much terser than Python for this.

Comment: @Arnauld I cannot get my head around this. Do you mind explaining how this code works?

Answer (score 12):

## LaTeX, 108/171

```
\newcounter{c}\def\s#1#2]{\stepcounter{c}\def\t{#2}\ifx\empty\t\arabic{c}\else#1\s#2]\fi}\def\q[#1]{\s#10]}
```

`\q[] //1`

Comment: Whoa, I don't think I've ever seen a latex answer on ppcg before.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

```js
f=(s,t=s,u=s+t.length)=>t==u?t:f(s,u)
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Comment: When I clicked on `Run Code Snippet` I get to see an error message. I have no knowledge of Javascript - I was just trying

Comment: @Prasanna Works for me in Firefox; which browser are you using?

Comment: @Prasanna Works on latest Google Chrome. Are you sure you aren't using IE11 or older, Opera or anything that doesn't support ES6?

Comment: I'm using an old good chrome (`Version 48.0.2564.97`). I will try this with IE too. Can't update my chrome - office security issues

Answer (score 5):

### Lua 5.2, 32 Bytes

```
a=arg[1]print(a..#a+#(''..#a+1))
```

Where the variable *a* is the input string.

Answer (score 5):

## C, <s>67</s> <s>65</s> 61 bytes

```c
x;f(*v){printf("%d",(int)log10(x=-~printf(v))*-~(x%10>8)+x);}
```

[Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vNFaprC3ZB9tthpp)

Comment: Ohh, yeah, I shoulda printf'd... Anyways, congrats on having the shorter C solution :D +1

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 57 bytes

```
#<>ToString[(a=Length@#)+(i=IntegerLength)[a+i@a]~Max~1]&
```

Unnamed function taking an array of characters as input and returning a string. Uses the fact that if `a` is the length of the input, then the number to append to the input is `a` plus the number of digits in (`a` + the length of `a`), rather than just `a` plus the number of digits of `a`. Unfortunately it wouldn't give the right answer for the empty-string input without the `~Max~1` special case.

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, 8 bytes ([old version](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/commit/894a88e818e5e86643765030ce5565246630671f))

```
.f+liq)+
```

Explanation:

```
.f    )  -  first where (i++)
  +      -    input + i
   l     -    len(^)
    iq   -   ^ == i
       + - input + ^
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.fDQ%2Blq%29%2B&input=aaaaaaaaa) (New version, 9 bytes)

Comment: It always confuses me how buried the actual output is among warnings or other messages :-)

Comment: I should really get around to fixing the web bug in the copy link that automatically disables the warnings switch

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>54</s> <s>48</s> 46 bytes

Simple solution. Recursion ended up being shorter.

```python
f=lambda s,n=0:f(s,n+1)if(s+`n`)[n:]else s+`n`
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqFCsk2drYJWmAaS1DTUzgQzthLwEzeg8q9jUnOJUBTD3f7FtUWJ5fGZeQWmJhiZXeUZmDlDGiouzoCgzr0QhTSO1LDFHo1hTk4sTReV/JSUupcTERAgJBkjMRCUA)

Comment: I think you can do ``(s+`n`)[n:]`` for ``n<len(s+`n`)``.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 46 bytes

```
f s=[l|i<-[0..],l<-[s++show i],length l==i]!!0
```

Usage example: `f "aaaaaaaa"` -> `"aaaaaaaa9"`.

Simply try all numbers starting with 0 and take the first that fits.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
l<L$@:?rc.lL,
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=bDxMJEA6P3JjLmxMLA&input=ImFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhIg&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

Basically a description of the problem. It will try every value of `L` bigger than the length of the input until it finds one for which, when concatenated to the input, is the length of that concatenation.

```
l<L              length(Input) < L
  L$@            Convert L to a string
     :?rc.       The Output is the concatenation of the Input with L as string
         .lL,    The length of the Output is L itself
```

Answer (score 3):

## Brainfuck, 258 bytes

```
,>+<----------[++++++++++>+[>+<-],----------]<[<]>[.>]>>>++++++++++<<[->+>-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<<]>>[-]>>>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]>>[>++++++[-<++++++++>]<.<<+>+>[-]]<[<[->-<]++++++[->++++++++<]>.[-]]<<++++++[-<++++++++>]<.[-]<<[-<+>]
```

The input must be terminated by a linefeed (LF). Only works for inputs with a length lesser than 256 (including the LF).

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LD4rPC0tLS0tLS0tLS1bKysrKysrKysrKz4rWz4rPC1dLC0tLS0tLS0tLS1dPFs8XT5bLj5dPj4-KysrKysrKysrKzw8Wy0-Kz4tWz4rPj5dPlsrWy08Kz5dPis-Pl08PDw8PDxdPj5bLV0-Pj4rKysrKysrKysrPFstPi1bPis-Pl0-WytbLTwrPl0-Kz4-XTw8PDw8XT5bLV0-Pls-KysrKysrWy08KysrKysrKys-XTwuPDwrPis-Wy1dXTxbPFstPi08XSsrKysrK1stPisrKysrKysrPF0-LlstXV08PCsrKysrK1stPCsrKysrKysrPl08LlstXTw8Wy08Kz5d&input=YWtkamduYm12bmRhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYW9namRuZXJ1NWpnYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhMTI1NDc4OTY1MmFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWIK)

### Explanation

```
# read first char and add one to cell #1
# the cell after the input will contain the length
,>+<
# subtract 10 to check for LF
----------
# while the input is not 10 (LF)
[
# restore the input to its original value
++++++++++
# add one to the length
>+
# cut and paste the length to the next cell, then read the input
[>+<-],
# subtract 10 to check for LF
----------
]
# for input abc, the tape here would be: a b c *0* 4
# rewind to the beginning of the input
<[<]>
# print the input string
[.>]>
# convert the length to ascii chars and output them
>>++++++++++<<[->+>-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<<]>>[-]>>>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-
<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]>>[>++++++[-<++++++++>]<.<<+>+>[-]]<[<[->-<]++++++[->++++++++
<]>.[-]]<<++++++[-<++++++++>]<.[-]<<[-<+>]
```

*Note: I used code from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13946554/1899794) to convert the length to ascii output; I hope this is acceptable on PPCG. This is my first Codegolf submission, and my second BF program. Feedback is welcomed.*

Comment: This isn't valid then, it must pass all test cases

Comment: So supporting a length up to 999 would be enough?

Comment: The spec says "arbitrary length" which means "as long as your language is capable of handling or without running out of memory"

Comment: The brainfuck interpreter you're using has 8-bit cells, so as long as your *algorithm* works for strings of arbitrary length, it should be fine if it fails for strings of length **256** or higher. The C and JavaScript submissions will also fail once the strings get too long.

Comment: Thank you Dennis, I will modify my submission accordingly

Comment: I modified the submission, hopefully it is valid now. Is it acceptable to "borrow" code from an SO answer like I did here?

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>46</s>  35 bytes

```perl6
{$_~(.chars,*.chars+.chars...{$^a==$^b})[*-1]}
```

```perl6
{$_~(.chars,*.chars+.chars...*)[2]}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#VVFBboMwELzziomKCiSOBUlVlSCSXnrovbeqihB1U1QCETZRURS@TteYCHraWc94dtaupcD5kaeRVRN6E1JFlnVscJ@WnwJxd7H3rcvT76SSbG7qwhTO@dx7X31cO5I/K7opEcO1gDXiLR4YIV@jgOEOL8eTaiBVlRUHIp40EWpJ2EsCDZ0kcHRHde30XC8L/J4NjdJfMcujjKc8KbAwc6n9KqtbiOUW9h4uNj@ice2sONVqmYvCY9ick7wWrl3W6nYIDxcypxWMklYYr6Bt8Voo7HaUycHvlJrNJl00WBhj7TGOmJgMI9p/tDYaW1oFyCT08w/hKfggYOCHTP/QtfsD)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{   # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  $_  # the input

  ~   # concatenated with

  (  # sequence generator

    .chars,  # the number of chars in ｢$_｣ (seed the generator)


    *\      # Whatever lambda input (represents previous value)
    .chars  # number of chars in that
    +       # plus
    .chars  # the number of chars in ｢$_｣


    ...     # keep doing that until

    *       # indefinitely

  )[2] # get the value at index 2 of the sequence
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 39 bytes

```python
lambda a:eval('a+str(len('*3+'a))))))')
```

Longer form:

```python
lambda a:a+str(len(a+str(len(a+str(len(a))))))
```

Iteratively in Python 2 (41 bytes):

```python
x=a=input();exec"x=a+`len(x)`;"*3;print x
```

Starting with `x` as the input string `a`, applies the transformation `x -> a + str(len(x))` three times. I'm still not clear why three applications are needed to always reach the fixed point.

Comment: Why 3 times? First to append the length of text, second to adjust the length to include the number, third in case that adjustment added an extra digit.

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 22 bytes

```
\G`
.
x
+r`\d*$
$._
x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/gf457ApcdVwaVdlBCToqXCpaIXD@T9/8@VmJgIwmAAZyCxkJk0ArS3gR5W0MWOUTAKRsEAgtFMPgpGwWguHwWjYBQMcQAA)

Ah well, if it wasn't for digits appearing in the input, this would be merely 11 bytes:

```
+r`\d*$
$._
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>61</s> 60 bytes

```hs
e=length
l%n|s<-show$l+1,n>e s=s|m<-n+1=(l+1)%m
c s=s++e s%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#y03MzLPNzCtJLUpMLlFI/p9qm5Oal16SwZWjmldTbKNbnJFfrpKjbaiTZ5eqUGxbXJNro5unbWirARTTVM3lSgYJamsD5VSN/v9PpD0AAA)

Recursive solution. Usage:

```
Prelude> c "aaaaaaaaa"
"aaaaaaaaa11"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <strike>62</strike> <strike>58</strike> 56 bytes

```
s=gets.chomp;p s+"#{(s+"#{(s+"#{s.size}").size}").size}"
```

Tested in `irb`.

There's probably a better way to do this, but this was the first thing I came up with. Any help in golfing would be appreciated.

**edit:** I realized my use of parentheses was excessive.

Comment: You only use `l` in one place. If you inline that, you will save 3 bytes `l=;`. But your solution will still be longer than mine ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
[¹¾JDg¾Q#¼\
```

Pretty straightforward bruteforce:

```
            Implicit i = 0
[           while true
 ¹¾J        Concatenate input and i -> str
    Dg¾Q#   Break if length(str) == i
         ¼\ Else, i += 1
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=W8K5wr5KRGfCvlEjwrxc&input=YWFhYWFhYWFh)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 42 bytes

```php
while(++$n<strlen($a=$argv[1].$n));echo$a;
```

Run with `-r`. Test [at OnlinePHPfunctions](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b48cf43d8f9bd339f5c94f23dbf26a57541d861).

Answer (score 2):

### bash, 47 bytes

```
 for((n=-1;${#s} != $n;));{ s=$1$[++n];};echo $s
```

Save this as a script, and pass the input string as an argument.

It's a brute force implementation: try each number in turn until you find one which works.

Answer (score 2):

## ><> (Fish) 35 bytes

```
i:1+?!v:o
ln;v9l<  >
*9+>:&)?!^1l&a
```

Takes input onto the stack, checks the length against values 9,99,999... and if the length is larger than add 1 to the stack length.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>43</s> 36 bytes

Anonymous function, [abusing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92066/4372) the `$.` global.

```rb
->s{$.+=1while(t=s+"#$.").size>$.;t}
```

Call it like this:

```rb
f = ->s{$.+=1while(t=s+"#$.").size>$.;t}
f[""]          # => "1"
f["a"]         # => "a2"
f["aaaaaaa"]   # => "aaaaaaa8"
f["aaaaaaaa"]  # => "aaaaaaaa9"
f["aaaaaaaaa"] # => "aaaaaaaaa11"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
LJL+LJ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQ4bmgIiwiIiwiTEpMK0xKIiwiIiwiYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYSJd)

Append the length of the string, take the length of that, then append the new length to the original. This does work with digit overflows (9, 99, etc...).

Comment: There's probably something I can do with iteratively adding and appending lengths until they are the same....

Comment: The code looks especially funny if you change the `+` to an `J`, which works fine: `LJLJLJ`

Comment: You actually don't need the `Ṡ` flag.

Comment: `3(LJ` for 4 bytes

Comment: oh..... but mine is funnier :p

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```lisp
L3Ya.#yy
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJMM1lhLiN5eSIsIiIsIiIsIlwiYWFhYWFhYWFhXCIiXQ==)

#### Explanation

Inspired by [Pacmanboss256's Vyxal solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252736/16766).

```lisp
          ;; y is empty string; a is first command-line argument (implicit)
L3        ;; Loop 3 times:
   a.     ;;  Concatenate a with
     #y   ;;  Length of y
  Y       ;;  Assign the result to y
       y  ;; After the loop, output y
```

Some worked examples:

```lisp
Input a        ""    "aaa"    "aaaaaaaaa"
Original y     ""    ""       ""
After loop 1   "0"   "aaa0"   "aaaaaaaaa0"
After loop 2   "1"   "aaa4"   "aaaaaaaaa10"
After loop 3   "1"   "aaa4"   "aaaaaaaaa11"
```

Comment: +1, neat loop setup

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 31 bytes

```
{$[9>t:#x;x,$1+t;x,$#x,($1+t)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pWiba0K7FSrrCu0FEx1C4BUcoVOhogtmZsLRdXWrRSYmKiUiyIASEToQCVh86F8aGUoVIsAKDMH2Y=)

*+22 bytes thanks to Dominic van Essen for pointing out a not-working test case (that should have worked)*

Comment: I think this fails for "aaaaaaaaa": it outputs "aaaaaaaaa10" which is 11 characters long...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen ohhhhhhhh... now I understand why.

Comment: fails for the longer test cases (i.e. you dont handle strings of length 99+)

Comment: `{x,$#x,$#x,$#x}` for 15 bytes i think?

Comment: `{{y,$#x}/4#,x}` for 14 bytes, maybe golfable further?

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
`G@Vhtn@>]&
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YEdAVmh0bkA-XSY&input=J2FhYWFhYWFhYSc) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YFhLCmBLQFZodG5APl0mClhETiR4VA&input=J2FhYScKJycKJ2FhYWFhYWFhJwonYWFhYWFhYWFhJwonYTEnCidhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYScKJ2FhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYSc).

```
`      % Do...while
  G    %   Push input
  @    %   Push iteration index (1-based)
  V    %   Convert number to string
  h    %   Concatenate horizontally
  t    %   Duplicate
  n    %   Get length of concatenated string
  @    %   Push iteration index
  >    %   True if length of concatenated string exceeds iteration index
]      % End. Run next iteration if top of stack is true; else exit loop
&      % Specifiy that next function (implicit display) takes only one input
       % Implicitly display top of the stack. This is the concatenated string
       % that had a length equal to the iteration index
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 77 bytes

```
n=>{int a=n.Length;int c=(a+1).ToString().Length-1;return(n+(n.Length+1+c));}
```

Comment: I don't now C#, but couldn't you use `return(n+(a+1+c))` as `a=n.Length` ?

Comment: And also drop the `-1` from `int c=(a+1).ToString().Length-1` and the `+1` from the return?

Comment: Wait, does this handle the larger test cases correctly? It looks like it returns `aa...a100` instead of `aa...a101` for the 99`a` test case.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 51 bytes (program)

## Ruby, 49 bytes (function)

Program (last newline is not necessary and thus unscored):

```
x=gets.strip
i=0
i+=1 until(y=x+i.to_s).size==i
p y
```

Function (last newline is scored):

```
def f x
i=0
i+=1 until(y=x+i.to_s).size==i
y
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 49 bytes

```
cat(a<-scan(,""),(t<-nchar(a))+nchar(t+1),sep='')
```

Pretty straightforward solution.

Comment: This doesn't work for me: `Read 1 item
Error in nchar(x + 1) : object 'x' not found`. I found that `(t<-nchar(a))+...` did work.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam : My bad !

Answer (score 1):

## Factor, 55 bytes

It's a walk in the park! I came up with this in my head as soon as I read the question.

```
[ dup length dup log10 ⌈ + >integer 10 >base append ]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Clojure, 72 bytes**

```
(defn f([s](f s 1))([s n](if(=(count(str s n))n)(str s n)(f s(inc n)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Wolfram, 56

```
#<>ToString@Nest[l+IntegerLength@#&,l=StringLength@#,2]&
```

Given `l = StringLength[x]` it appends `l + IntegerLength[l + IntegerLength[l]]` to `x`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](http://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), <strike>48</strike> <strike>45</strike> 41 bytes

```
)"   10/{:@!
.,;: _ { _ ;
   })"}) 10-9!@
```

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=KSIgICAxMC97OkAhCi4sOzogXyB7IF8gOwogICB9KSJ9KSAxMC05IUA&input=YWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWE)

Saved 4 bytes thanked to @Martin Ender

Answer (score 1):

## ForceLang, 83 bytes

```
set s io.readln()
label 1
set n 1+n
set t s+n
if t.len=n
 io.write t
 exit()
goto 1
```

Answer (score 1):

### awk, 37 bytes

```
{FS="";r=$0;$0=r NF;$0=r NF;$0=r NF}1
```

That will work in any awk that splits lines into characters when FS is NULL e.g. GNU awk and most others. WIth other awks you'd have to use the `length()` function instead of `NF` to calculate the number of characters in the record, e.g. `awk '{r=$0;$0=r length;$0=r length;$0=r length}1' file`.

Breakdown:

```
FS=""    # split the record at every character so NF is a count of characters in the record
r=$0     # save the original record
$0=r NF  # append the original length to the original record and cause awk to recalculate NF
$0=r NF  # append the new length to the original record and cause awk to recalculate NF again
$0=r NF  # append the final length to the original record for output
1        # a true condition invoking awks default action of printing the current record
```

Example:

```
$ awk '{FS="";r=$0;$0=r NF;$0=r NF;$0=r NF}1' file
aaa4
1
aaaaaaaa9
aaaaaaaaa11
a13
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa101
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa102
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

Many thanks to Dennis for his help in writing this answer. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@9ifWizjy2Xz@F2Q2Vrh////ycmJaekpqVnZGZl5@Tm5RcUFhWXlJaVV1RWUUsGAA)

```
D;³L=
LÇ1#;@
```

**Explanation**

```
LÇ1#;@  Main link. Argument: s
          Runs the helper link until a suitable x is found.
L       Yields the length of s.
 Ç1#    Calls the helper link until one match is found.
    ;@  Appends the matching x to s.

D;³L=  Helper link. Argument: x
         Appends x to s and checks if its length is equal to x.
D      Convert x from integer to decimal.
 ;³    Append to our original string.
   L=  Check if the length of this new string is equal to x.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 31 bytes

Just going through all the numbers until one fits:

```
perl -lpe '1while++$n<length$_.$n;$_.=$n'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 47 bytes

```
[ dup length dup log10 ⌈ + 1 /i >dec append ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY09jsJADIV7TvFEi_hJh7ISEhWKtKJBVIhiduKE0QZnmPEI0VBTcAOaNLtH4C5pOQmBwcWz_fk9-fZfKC21a9rzepUtFyl-yTFV8HQIxJo89kp2bxkFNrrOKS5FYC2mZg_ryBNLxFY5T-7FRE7WmY5_9bJlCtkZLnvz72y-SjHLSYPD_ofczEvnKv-CFMNpO94gDxYVcdl9fY91mUzwuF4wQIKxiVllLXGObYzd--pTffijstCqqjCKx6aJ_Qk)

small improvement to the previous answer.

`>dec` is polyfilled since it is a newer addition.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), <s>26</s> 14 bytes

```
iysp&ol`Syl+u;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zsrhALT8nIbgyR7vU@v//RBgAAA)

This turned out to be trickier than I expected...  Since strings of length 9, 99, etc... need an extra digit when the length it appended.

So the code computes the number of digits in the length of a string composed of the original string plus the length of that string.  Then that length is added to the length of the original string to get the final length, which is appended to the original.

```
iysp&ol`Syl+u; - 
i              - read in the input string
 ysp           - get the length, stash it, delete from stack
    &o         - print the string
      l`       - load the string length and increment
        Sy     - split to digit, count them
          l+   - load the string length and add to digit count
            u; - print as number and exit (to avoid printing stack)
```

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 40 bytes

```
.+"\(length+(length+1|tostring|length))"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/19PWylGIyc1L70kQxtGG9aU5BeXFGXmpddARDQ1lf7/V0qEAaX/ukUA)

It's the same algorithm, just in `jq` for comparison.  I couldn't find a shorter way to do it in `jq` even though using "length" three times seems like it should be golf-able...

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
3{l+
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPTMlN0JsJTJCJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9YWFhYWFhYWEmZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
3{l+  # Implicit input
3{    # Repeat three times:
  l   #  Take the length of the top
      #  of stack (initially input)
   +  #  And append this to the input
      # (Three times is enough to handle
      #  digit overflows like 9, 99, etc.)
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 75 bytes

Yes, there's another C answer but this (the same method as my Factor answer) is shorter:

```
i,z;f(char*s){i=strlen(s);z=1+log10(i);sprintf(realloc(s,i+z)+i,"%d",i+z);}
```

Ungolfed:

```
i, z;

g (char* s){
  i = strlen(s);
  z = 1 + log10(i);
  s = realloc(s, i + z);
  sprintf(s + i, "%d", i + z);
}
```

`ceil(log10(n)` is the number of digits in base 10 `n`, but `1+` is shorter than `ceil()`.

Then, resize the string so we don't get a segfault, and format the number after the string part.

Comment: I don't believe this method works for 98 or 997

Answer (score 0):

**Under review**

**Powershell V2.0, 64 bytes**

```
$s=$args[0]
$s+[string]($s.length+([string]($s.length)).length)
```

**Example**

```
PS C:\Users\***\Downloads\golf> .\str-length.ps1 'This is my strin3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
33333333333333333333333333333333333333333g'
This is my strin333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333g113
```

Comment: This outputs `aaaaaaaaa10` when given input `aaaaaaaaa`, and not the correct `aaaaaaaaa11`.

Comment: You're right, I missed that somehow.

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 75 bytes

```
def a(b:String,c:Int=0):String=if((b+c).length>c)a(b,c+1)else b+c
```

Answer (score 0):

### awk, 27 bytes

```
$0=$0length($0length($0NF))
```

Test it:

```
$ awk -F '' '$0=$0length($0length($0NF))' file
7aaaaaa8
8aaaaaaa9
9aaaaaaaa11
97aaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa99
98aaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa10aaaaaaaa101
```

Comment: You can change `length($0)` to just `length` for brevity.

Comment: @EdMorton Been experimenting with `awk -F '' '$0=NF'`

Answer (score 0):

## C# / CS Script <s>99</s> <s>87</s> 79 bytes

Saved a few bytes switching to a lambda.
And a few more moving the try/catch out of the for loop.

```c#
F=a=>{int i=0,l;try{for(;;)l=(a+(a+a.Length).Length)[++i];}catch{}return a+i;};
```

[Try it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/08CLkk)

Expanded:

```c#
F => a
{
    // 'i' is for traversing the string
    // 'l' is just a placeholder
    int i = 0, l;

    // wrap the loop in a try/catch
    try
    {
        // loop forever
        for (;;)
            // assign to 'l' the char at position ++i
            // throws an IndexOutOfRangeException when it falls off the end
            l = (a + (a + a.Length).Length)[++i];
    }
    // empty catch block
    catch {}

    // returns a string concat of the input a and index i
    return a + i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 67 bytes

```
String y(String y){int i=0;for(;(y+i).length()!=i;i++);return y+i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#xY4xC4MwEIV3f8XVKUEI7Rwc/A2OpcNpU3sQo5izJYi/3QZqV@tS@m64g/fx3tUWvYcCpqXkgVwDQXwOOZFjoPyob90gtAgZSWWNa/gu5CEnTVkm9WB4HBxEU89LP1aWavCMHNejoyu0SG6NPF9QTkksqyAHZ55QCKkTKINn06puZNVHjK0TlQoiRcRUbgHbLq7aR33DTjtjfqZ/978fmOMsLw)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
3Fg«
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f2C390Or//xOhAAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeXhCS7/jd3SD63@X6vzP1opMTFRSUcJiBKhAIkJZhsiC9AM0MWSRKVYAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
3F    # Loop 3 times:
  g   #  Pop the current string, and push its length
      #  (which will use the implicit input-string in the first iteration)
   «  #  Append this length to the (implicit) input-string
      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously similar to a port of @lyxal's [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103377/appending-string-lengths/255215#comment564122_252736).

Comment: @Neil Your link goes to the question itself instead of a comment? But looking for _Lyxal_'s comment I assume you mean [this one on the Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103377/appending-string-lengths?page=1&tab=scoredesc#comment564122_252736)? It indeed appears to be the same, even though I came up with it independently a few hours ago. It's a pretty straight-forward approach when you use `g«` twice in a row and see that the 98-long test case requires a third `g«` tbh. 

Comment: Huh, your comment doesn't work for me, but I'll take your word for both your claims.

Comment: @Neil Huh? Your linked comment didn't work for me though.. :/

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 29 bytes

```javascript
s=>(g=x=>s+x.length)(g(g(s)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1k4j3bbC1q5Yu0IvJzUvvSRDUyMdCIs1NTX/J@fnFefnpOrl5KdrpGkkJMJAAlAOAA)