# Binary to trinary

Tags: code-golf, parsing

## The problem

Given a binary number from 0 to 111111 convert it to trinary. (Base 3). Then print the result.

### Rules

No using a list of conversions.

Don't cheat

You must use a string as the number

No compressing the input string As I will be testing the code with several different numbers I can't use compressed strings

### Notes

By trinary I mean counting in base 3. So 0,1,2,10,11,12,20... ect

Leading zeros will be present 001101

Most important number is on the left.

### Example

```
String input = "110111"
String a = code(input);
print(a);
```

## To win

This is code golf!

Do it correctly and in the smallest size.

Comment: `You must use a string as the number` I'd recommend allowing other formats such as integer etc.

Comment: Base 3 is more commonly referred to as [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system).

Comment: I'm not sure what *No using a list of conversions.* means. Are you disallowing base conversion built-ins?

Comment: It's even less clear what "no compression" is supposed to refer to.

Comment: We have a [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) where you can have feedback and help from the community before posting a challenge. Please use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bash 25 bytes

**Golfed**

```
bc<<<"ibase=2;obase=3;$1"
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 26 bytes

```js
s=>(+`0b${s}`).toString(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <del>97</del> 87 bytes

```
f=->a{x=0
a.chars.map{|i|x+=x+i.ord%2}
o=x>0?"":?0
(o=(48+x%3).chr+o
x/=3)while x>0
o}
```

Old version:

```
def f a
x=0
a.chars.map{|i|x=x+x+i.ord%2}
o=x>0?"":"0"
while x>0
o=(48+x%3).chr+o
x/=3
end
o
end
```

Comment: Unless you were purposefully avoiding builtins, I think you're overthinking this. 21 bytes: `->s{s.to_i(2).to_s 3}`. Also you might find this useful: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/363/11261

Comment: @Jordan Indeed I was avoiding built-in base conversion functions.

Comment: @Jordan Thanks for the tip list I have applied some of them and trimmed off 10 bytes.