# Sever-sort an array

Tags: code-golf, array, sorting

### Challenge

Given a non-empty array of integers, e.g.:

```
[5, 2, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3]
```

First sever it into arrays where no item is larger than the previous (i.e. non-ascending arrays):

```
[5, 2] [7, 6, 4, 1] [3]
```

Next, reverse each array:

```
[2, 5] [1, 4, 6, 7] [3]
```

Finally, concatenate them all together:

```
[2, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7, 3]
```

This should be what your program outputs/function returns. Repeat this procedure enough times and the array will be fully sorted.

### Rules

- Input and output may be given through any standard methods, and may be in any reasonable array format.
- The input array will never be empty, but may contain negatives and/or duplicates.
- The absolute value of each integer will always be less than 2<sup>31</sup>.

### Test cases

Hopefully these cover all edge cases:

```
[1] -> [1]
[1, 1] -> [1, 1]
[1, 2] -> [1, 2]
[2, 1] -> [1, 2]
[2, 3, 1] -> [2, 1, 3]
[2, 1, 3] -> [1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 2] -> [1, 2, 2]
[2, 1, 1] -> [1, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 1, 2] -> [1, 1, 3, 2]
[3, 2, 1, 2] -> [1, 2, 3, 2]
[3, 1, 2, 2] -> [1, 3, 2, 2]
[1, 3, 2, 2] -> [1, 2, 2, 3]
[1, 0, 5, -234] -> [0, 1, -234, 5]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1] -> [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 1, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 1, 5, 4] -> [2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 1, 4, 2, 3] -> [1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
[5, 2, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3] -> [2, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7, 3]
[-5, -2, -7, -6, -4, -1, -3] -> [-5, -7, -2, -6, -4, -3, -1]
[14, 5, 3, 8, 15, 7, 4, 19, 12, 0, 2, 18, 6, 11, 13, 1, 17, 16, 10, 9] -> [3, 5, 14, 8, 4, 7, 15, 0, 12, 19, 2, 6, 18, 11, 1, 13, 9, 10, 16, 17]
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **the shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: What's the big-o of this sorting method?

Comment: @mbomb007 I don't understand big-o notation very well, but I think a single iteration is O(n). Multiply that by worst-case n iterations and you get O(n^2) (worst-case; best-case would be O(n), I think, for a single iteration).

Comment: That sounds right to me, however it's worth pointing out that reversing an array isn't a very efficient operation, so it's a slow `O(n^2)`

Comment: @WheatWizard reversing an array doesn't require room for a copy of the array, only room for a single element. and is `O(n)`.   swap first and last elements then swap second and second last elements etc, when you get to the middle stop.

Comment: Reversing is `O(n)`, but reversing can be built right into the algorithm (that's what my JS answer does); since each iteration loops over each item in the array once, a single iteration is `O(n)`. (I think...)

Comment: It's definitely `O(n^2)`.  Rotating a sorted array by 1 causes causes the `O(n^2)` lower bound (`[2,3,4,5,6,1]`).  However the upper bound is also `O(n^2)` (assuming a good implementation), as it is strictly better than bubble sort (as it swaps two numbers + possibly more)

Comment: Here are the [average number of severs](http://pastebin.com/9DxLF305) for random list sizes from 1-20. Each one was run 10000 times, with the total severs counted, and then an average calculated. Note that the "random lists"  were filled with uniform random elements 1-100.

Answer (score 19):

## JavaScript (ES6), 64 bytes

```
f=([n,...a],z=[],q=[n,...z])=>a+a?n<a[0]?[...q,...f(a)]:f(a,q):q
```

Recursion FTW! The basic algorithm in use here is to keep track of the current non-ascending run in an array, "returning" it whenever an ascending element is found. We do this recursively, continually concatenating the results, until we run out of items. By creating each run in reverse (`[n,...z]` instead of `[...z,n]`), we can avoid the lengthy `.reverse()` at no cost.

#### Test snippet

```js
f=([n,...a],z=[],q=[n,...z])=>a+a?n<a[0]?[...q,...f(a)]:f(a,q):q

g=a=>console.log("Input:",`[${a}]`,"Output:",`[${f(a)}]`)

g([1])
g([1,1])
g([1,2])
g([2,1])
g([3,2,1])
g([3,1,2])
g([3,1,1,2])
g([5,2,7,6,4,1,3])
```

```html
<input id=I value="5, 2, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3">
<button onclick="g((I.value.match(/\d+/g)||[]).map(Number))">Run</button>
```

Comment: Can you explain how your array gets parsed into your first parameter `[n,...a]`. What is `n`? Is that just the first item in your array?

Comment: @obarakon Correct. `n` is the first item in the array, and `a` is the rest of the array. You can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. Since your first parameter is an array, why do you need to include the `...a`? Is that just so you can take advantage of `n`? One more thing, when you call `f(a,q)`, does `q` get set to the parameter `z`?

Comment: @obarakon Well, `f=([n])=>...` would only capture the first element, and `f=([n,a])=>...` would capture only the first in `n` and the second in `a`. Another way to do what `f=([n,...a])=>,,,` does would be `f=a=>(n=a.unshift(),...`.

Comment: And since `z` is the second parameter in the function, when `f(a,q)` is called, `f` sees it as `z`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 63 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,*p:x[:1]>p>()and p+f(x)or x and f(x[1:],x[0],*p)or p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#VVFBjoMwDDx3X@FbSetIdQItIC0fQRxYVUiVdtmo6iG/Z23XVbaHJOOZsTOEbfn8nn@@rjNkPKQ@jz1NQxoqN69XSMelyu73Dhmk5GKkfsI8niY2i5C2ReXbChWhQ9mB7AxyBqv5jAWyGgsMBaohPqEJXIW3ipQIdkt8q04IDYIPsS6E7a9U2lKzT4hGoV1RYhj9L/iTsxZSOZijUXhBOCv9@javQXix4lnyrHkWvapU60Qe3XJLo/3S3PEKGliStDqU5DXsUdhGQrGhc/3HLt1v66PKCHs/7FH@kXPbHw)

Answer (score 11):

### JavaScript (ES6), 70 bytes

Sure, this is already beaten by [ETHproductions answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104135/58563), but that's the best I could come up with so far without using recursion.

```js
a=>a.map((n,i)=>a[x=[...o,...r=[n,...r]],i+1]>n&&(o=x,r=[]),r=o=[])&&x
```

*Note:* Initializing both `r` and `o` to the exact same object with `r = o = []` may look like a hazardous idea. But it is safe to do so here because `r` is immediately assigned its own instance (containing the first element of `a`) on the first iteration with `r = [n, ...r]`.

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>a.map((n,i)=>a[x=[...o,...r=[n,...r]],i+1]>n&&(o=x,r=[]),r=o=[])&&x

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 1])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 2])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([2, 1])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([2, 3, 1])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([2, 1, 3])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([2, 1, 2])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([2, 1, 1])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([3, 1, 1, 2])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([3, 2, 1, 2])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([3, 1, 2, 2])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 3, 2, 2])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 0, 5, -234])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 0, 1, 0, 1])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([2, 1, 5, 4, 3])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([2, 3, 1, 5, 4])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([5, 1, 4, 2, 3])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([5, 2, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([-5, -2, -7, -6, -4, -1, -3])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([14, 5, 3, 8, 15, 7, 4, 19, 12, 0, 2, 18, 6, 11, 13, 1, 17, 16, 10, 9])));
```

Comment: No worries, I love seeing different approaches. And one often ends up becoming shorter than another after golfing :-)

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
Ṁ;<œṗ³UF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wZ4O1zdHJD3dOP7Q51O3////RhiY6CqY6CsY6ChY6CoZAlrmOAlDI0BKIjXQUDHQUgKQhUM4MSBkCMVAliAIqMwQJARVYxgIA)

### Explanation:

```
Ṁ;         Prepend the list [a1, a2… an] with its maximum.
  <        Elementwise compare this with the original list:
           [max(a) < a1, a1 < a2, …, a(n-1) < an, an]
           The first element is always 0.
   œṗ³     Partition the original list (³) at the indices
           of the non-zero values in the working list.
           (The spurious `an` at the end of the left argument,
           resulting from comparing lists of different sizes,
           is ignored by this operation, thankfully.)
      U    Reverse each part.
       F   Flatten.
```

Comment: I was on the verge of hitting *Save Edits* when I saw your answer... Well done.

Comment: @Dennis Heh, so you added Dyalog partitioned enclose, but what about APL2 partition?

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
lidO>vYsGhXSOZ)
```

Input is a column vector, with the format `[5; 2; 7; 6; 4; 1; 3]` (semicolon is the row separator).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@5@TmeJvVxZZ7J4REewfpfn/f7SptYKRtYK5tYKZtYKJtYKhtYJxLAA)

Take input `[5; 2; 7; 6; 4; 1; 3]` as an example.

#### Explanation

```
l     % Push 1
      % STACK: 1
i     % Push input
      % STACK: 1, [5; 2; 7; 6; 4; 1; 3]
d     % Consecutive differences
      % STACK: 1, [-3; 5; -1; -2; -3; 2]
O>    % Test if greater than 0, element-wise
      % STACK: 1, [0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1]
v     % Concatenate vertically
      % STACK: [1; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1]
Ys    % Cumulative sum
      % STACK: [1; 1; 2; 2; 2; 2; 3]
G     % Push input again
      % STACK: [1; 1; 2; 2; 2; 2; 3], [5; 2; 7; 6; 4; 1; 3]
h     % Concatenate horizontally
      % STACK: [1 5; 1 2; 2 7; 2 6; 2 4; 2 1; 3 3]
XS    % Sort rows in lexicographical order
      % STACK: [1 2; 1 5; 2 1; 2 4; 2 6; 2 7; 3 3]
OZ)   % Get last column. Implicitly display
      % STACK: [2; 5; 1; 4; 6; 7; 3]
```

Comment: I translated your answer to Octave saved me 31 bytes!

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, <s>30</s> 27 bytes

<sup>*3 bytes saved due to [@Martin Ender](http://ppcg.lol/users/8478).*</sup>

```
Join@@Sort/@Split[#,#>#2&]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a list of numbers as input and returns a list of numbers as output.

Comment: Beat me to it! :)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> <s>16</s> 14 bytes

Saved 2 bytes using [Luis Mendo's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104123/47066) sorting trick

```
ü‹X¸ì.pO¹)ø{ø¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394z6OGnRGHdhxeo1fgf2in5uEd1Yd3HFry/3@0oYmOgqmOgrGOgoWOgiGQZa6jABQytARiIx0FAx0FIGkIlDMDUoZADFQJooDKDEFCQAWWsQA)

**Explanation**

Example input `[5, 2, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3]`

```
ü‹               # pair-wise less-than
                 # STACK: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
  X¸ì            # prepend a 1
                 # STACK: [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
     .p          # prefixes
       O         # sum
                 # STACK: [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
        ¹        # push input
                 # STACK: [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [5, 2, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3]
         )       # wrap stack in list
                 # STACK: [[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [5, 2, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3]]
          ø      # zip
                 # STACK: [[1, 5], [1, 2], [2, 7], [2, 6], [2, 4], [2, 1], [3, 3]]
           {     # sort
                 # STACK: [[1, 2], [1, 5], [2, 1], [2, 4], [2, 6], [2, 7], [3, 3]]
            ø    # zip
                 # STACK: [[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7, 3]]
             ¤   # tail
                 # OUTPUT: [2, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7, 3]
```

**Previous 16 byte solution**

```
Dü‹X¸ì.pO.¡€g£í˜
```

Comment: Those linebreaks explained it wonderfully... :-P

Comment: @StewieGriffin: Yeah, I changed up the code and posted before I had rewritten the explanation :P

Comment: I know this is 7 years old, but for anyone else coming across this, it can be 9 bytes now using the same approach: [`ü‹.¥øí{øθ`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8J5HDTv1Di09vOPw2urDO87t@P8/2tBER8FUR8FYR8FCR8EQyDLXUQAKGVoCsZGOgoGOApA0BMqZASlDIAaqBFFAZYYgIaACy1gA).

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 100 bytes

A really terrible golf, but I wanted to post my solution [*(one does not simply outgolf Dennis)*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104142/60919)...

```py
d=input();L=[];x=0;d+=-~d[-1],
for i in range(1,len(d)):
 if d[i]>d[i-1]:L+=d[x:i][::-1];x=i
print L
```

[**Test on repl.it!**](https://repl.it/EvQM/0)

Input should be given as a Python list literal, such as `[5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 1]`.

The basic idea is to make heavy use of Python's slicing syntax, slicing each necessary section from the array, reversing it, and adding it to the new array.

Comment: I think the first line can be `d,L,x=input(),[],0;d+=...`.

Comment: @Dopapp that's exactly the same byte count

Answer (score 4):

### Pyke, <s>11</s> 8 bytes ([old version](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/commit/98f0079d7cb3d9e837dc1b36e9f7b4f5cd051f43))

```
$0m<fm_s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%240m%3C0R%2Bfm_s&input=%5B5%2C+2%2C+7%2C+6%2C+4%2C+1%2C+3%5D) (works on latest version)

```
$        -     delta(input)
 0m<     -    map(i<0 for i in ^)
    f    -   split_at(input, ^)
     m_  -  map(reverse, ^)
       s - sum(^)
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ECMA 6), <s>121</s> <s>128</s> <s>125</s> <s>119</s> 108 bytes

```
f=a=>{p=a[0],c=[],b=[];for(e of a){e>p&&b.push(c.reverse(c=[]));c.push(p=e)}return[].concat.call([],...b,c)}
```

Lambda expression takes a single `Array` parameter, `a`.

*Thanks to @ETHproductions for helping me see my first mistake.*

Comment: Nice! I think you can do ``return(b+","+c).split`,` `` to save a few bytes at the end.

Comment: Better yet, you can use `c.unshift` instead of `c.push` to remove the need to reverse `c`. After doing this, I got [94 bytes](http://ethproductions.github.io/bytes/?e=utf-8&t=f%3Da%3D%3E%7Bp%3Da%5B0%5D%2Cc%3D%5B%5D%2Cb%3D%5B%5D%3Bfor%28e%20of%20a%29%7Be%3Ep%26%26%28b%3D%5B%2E%2E%2Eb%2C%2E%2E%2Ec%5D%2Cc%3D%5B%5D%29%3Bc%2Eunshift%28p%3De%29%7Dreturn%5B%2E%2E%2Eb%2C%2E%2E%2Ec%5D%7D).

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 163 bytes

Yes, I know how horrid this is. Supporting zeros and negatives was *super* fun. Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
\d+
$*
(?<=-1*)1
x
-

x,1
x¶1
\b(1+),(1+\1)\b
$1¶$2
,,1
,¶1
x,(¶|$)
x¶¶
(?<=\b\1x+(?=,(x+))),\b
¶
O%$#`.(?=(.*))
$.1
+`¶
,
\bx
-x
(\w+)
$.1
^,
0,
,$
,0
,,
,0,
^$
0
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#JY3RDcIwDET/bw2CFDeXKi4Ffqg6AgtEVVWxA/lgrgyQxYoLsnSy3tl3e34FuA5@fkxRO1EURKDQllYVefMahCZZJW9w2qobQPN5@IW@1Y@T47rVX0zespbg54m@BBGhvZn1PLvT2hv2fScC1yvCapzWYZ0FPr/Dny9EIujAZE2mxOKQ9v3KwSYx3hkH3jhSGS8GlOMX)

**Explanation:**

```
\d+                         # Convert to unary
$*
(?<=-1*)1                   # Replace negatives with x's instead of 1's
x
-                           # Remove minus sign

x,1                         # Separate if negative before positive
x¶1
\b(1+),(1+\1)\b             # or greater positive follows a positive
$1¶$2
,,1                         # or positive follows a zero
,¶1
x,(¶|$)                     # or zero follows a negative
x¶¶
(?<=\b\1x+(?=,(x+))),\b     # or negative follows a negative of greater magnitude.
¶
O%$#`.(?=(.*))              # Swear at the input, then reverse each line
$.1
+`¶                         # Remove breaks, putting commas back
,
\bx                         # Put the minus signs back
-x
(\w+)                       # Replace unary with length of match (decimal)
$.1
^,                          # Do a bunch of replacements to resurrect lost zeros
0,
,$
,0
,,
,0,
^$
0
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>60</s> 55 bytes

```
s=->x{x.slice_when{|p,q|p<q}.map{|z|z.reverse}.flatten}
```

Pretty much what the challenge asked for. I defined a lambda `s`, that takes an array `x`, and *sever* (slices) it into smaller pieces where the following element would be greater than. This gives back an enumerator, which we can call map on and *reverse* the order of the pieces, before finally bringing it all together with flatten, which *concatenates* the elements in the defined order into one array.

Tests

```
p s[[1]]===[1]
p s[[1, 1]]===[1, 1]
p s[[1, 2]]===[1, 2]
p s[[2, 1]]===[1, 2]
p s[[2, 3, 1]]===[2, 1, 3]
p s[[2, 1, 3]]===[1, 2, 3]
p s[[2, 1, 2]]===[1, 2, 2]
p s[[2, 1, 1]]===[1, 1, 2]
p s[[3, 1, 1, 2]]===[1, 1, 3, 2]
p s[[3, 2, 1, 2]]===[1, 2, 3, 2]
p s[[3, 1, 2, 2]]===[1, 3, 2, 2]
p s[[1, 3, 2, 2]]===[1, 2, 2, 3]
p s[[1, 0, 5, -234]]===[0, 1, -234, 5]
p s[[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]===[0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
p s[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]===[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
p s[[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]===[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
p s[[2, 1, 5, 4, 3]]===[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
p s[[2, 3, 1, 5, 4]]===[2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
p s[[5, 1, 4, 2, 3]]===[1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
p s[[5, 2, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3]]===[2, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7, 3]
p s[[-5, -2, -7, -6, -4, -1, -3]]===[-5, -7, -2, -6, -4, -3, -1]
p s[[14, 5, 3, 8, 15, 7, 4, 19, 12, 0, 2, 18, 6, 11, 13, 1, 17, 16, 10, 9]]===[3, 5, 14, 8, 4, 7, 15, 0, 12, 19, 2, 6, 18, 11, 1, 13, 9, 10, 16, 17]
```

Comment: Welcome, nice <s>first</s> second answer, check this: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks a lot. Turned this into a lambda, as suggested in the link you provided, and saved 5 bytes that way.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
~c:{>=r}ac
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=fmM6ez49cn1hYw&input=WzU6Mjo3OjY6NDoxOjNd&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

```
~c            Deconcatenate the Input
  :{>=r}a     Each resulting sublist must be non-increasing, and then reverse it
         c    Concatenate
```

Comment: Does Brachylog's `c`, when run in reverse, necessarily try splits into fewer lists first?

Comment: @ais523 yes, it does.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
ṁ↔ġ≤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU@7DcIwEN0lVZCepZwd59MwAC1llBIJCVFFDBAKJHoWQMoStIhFyCLm@WJS2O/j872742U4hXO@f0/5LjPb7LAZ5usYvq9xvj0@z/k@hRC6Tnp0guW2vK1yC5dQ4BKmV/VdRHUc7MqIyvhnZQU8jHVlEnqWMBaV8OSeqG1SgOr/EFFpjdC16ntijYp6Gc7EBJgapoIpYQQm2sLu7NBAPMtZ3EIs4xnR8LdwA12jhlAVaPv@Bw)

I've `ġ`ot `ṁ`yself the right tools for this job.

#### Explanation

`ġ` is "groupby": it divides a list into sublists where in each sublist the given function returns a truthy value for any pair of elements. Used with `≤`, this divides the list into non-increasing sequences.

`ṁ` is "concatmap": it maps a function to each element of a list, and concatenates the results together. With `↔` (reverse), this performs the reverse-and-concatenate final part of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>7</s> 15 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Requires `⎕ML←3`, which is default on many systems.*

```apl
{∊⌽¨⍵⊂⍨1+⍵-⌊/⍵}
```

`∊` enlist (flatten)

`⌽¨` each-reversed

`⍵⊂⍨` the argument partitioned* by cutting where each corresponding element is larger than its predecessor in

`1+` one plus

`⍵-` the argument minus

`⌊/⍵` the smallest element of the argument

---

Old 7 byte solution fails with non-positive integers:

Requires `⎕ML←3`, which is default on many systems.*

```apl
∊⌽¨⊆⍨⎕
```

`∊` enlist (flatten) the

`⌽¨` each-reversed

`⊂⍨` self-partitioned*

---

* Partition (`⊂`) is a function which cuts its right argument where the corresponding left argument is larger than the preceding one. (Unfortunately it only accepts non-negative integers, and zero has special meaning.) From version 16, this functionality of `⊂` is available on all systems (even those where `⎕ML≠3`), using the glyph `⊆`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
<Ɲk$UF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZI9UsQwDIX7nMIzUNozsZxskhmGkhtQMDspaWAvQEtDT7UNN@AC1AzcAy5ipCfh9ZqfIrvW06cnWcnN9W53l/PZ@9Pt6eVFfn34vH9@e/x42fP/Vc7bbhtX705cOHd84si7SpAAGtUasUYNZ1qqZWFYMlpOdUGdoSZDJXM8jGaSZpqyiO6W/9021fXU5FPpXAXNWDozB713o3eB0lCQHq4ica5Q9ttQvd2tOwyGqh/jmteIk93rT0ovbex/VCpg@67qjhEBNV4jpEE3ocHk3QbS0TsmsGqyASQVAWvjh@PAcuBskL0dCoFMhn0jSTDZ1wBbDmc2H@ErnRd@CIuVm8xoGWXH9rEwFkViYCmdko44wGyAl1j26iWepEazmanfoj7wm9Zu/QI)

### How it works

```
<Ɲk$UF - Main link. Takes an array A on the left
   $   - To A:
 Ɲ     -   For each overlapping pair of elements [a, b] in A:
<      -     Is a < b?
  k    -   Partition A at the truthy elements
    U  - Reverse each subarray
     F - Flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 49 bytes

```
(a:b)%l|any(<a)l=l++b%[a]|1<2=b%(a:l)
_%l=l
(%[])
```

Usage example: `(%[]) [5,2,7,6,4,1,3]` -> `[2,5,1,4,6,7,3]`.

Recursive approach. The function `%` takes the input list as its first parameter and an accumulator `l` which keeps track of the non-ascending chunk so far (in reverse order). The base case is reached when the input list is empty and then the result is the accumulator. If the input list is not empty and the first element `a` doesn't fit in the current chunk (`any(<a)l`), return the accumulator and append a recursive call on the rest of the list and `a` as the new accumulator (`l++b%[a]`). Else, make a recursive call on the rest of the list and `a` prepended to tha accumulator (`b%(a:l)`). The main function `(%[])` calls `%` with an empty accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

### R, 64 bytes

```
cat(unlist(lapply(split(x<-scan(),cumsum(c(F,diff(x)>0))),rev)))
```

Reads input from stdin. We split the input into a list of vectors using `split()` which requires a factor variable that groups the input. The factor is created by taking the cumulative sum of the the logical vector for which the difference is positive.

Consider the vector:

```
x=c(5, 2, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3)
```

Now taking the difference and prepending `F` by running `y=c(F,diff(x)>0)` would produce the following logical vector:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Taking the cumulative sum `cumsum(y)` produces a vector where each group is represented by a unique factor upon which we can combine with the `split` function:

```
[1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 2
```

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcVLCoAgEADQq8xyBgz6t4nuIpYwMIioiZ1@pLd5SdXZgm8QzgXFxigf5ihcsJ1DdjYgmZu951DxHxtdI5FJTyUi3WCGA3ZYYYJFOw) using `diffinv` rather than `cumsum`.

Answer (score 1):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 98 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
$

-(\d+)
$1$*-/
\d+
$*
S-`(?<=(-+)/ )(?!\1)|(?=\b(1+))(?<!\2 )
O%`\S* 
¶

((-)|1)*/? 
$2$#1 
 $
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#LU5LrsIwDNz7FINekJJWVnHSUpBAXb4lC7ZZVIhjcC4OwMX6Jn4sPJ7xZ@x9/F23IBCN9dknCRY6HYRcQid3XeNyuUbt04AUl1219IrLtT6i9YmFy65mJLnt13rvIJ@3SIyaXpa6YYGEHH4MgiDbZmJokSUzZxRHQ3H0KiulIVVB/mYiM@e@@YAJmsvo1KOZsj1ikonoq27n6v9U4@waK9RkGTOOVO0BbY7QGXqEjlCDFjH6cfMEmzjKwTMs8xyNT9w0/unPzjCqA85/)

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, <s>75</s> 44 bytes

Based on [MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104123/62451) of @LuisMendo

```
@(a)sortrows([cumsum([1;diff(a)>0]),a])(:,2)
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/#bT0RW)

Previous answer

```
@(a)[fliplr(mat2cell(f=fliplr(a),1,diff(find([1,diff(f)<0,numel(a)])))){:}]
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/#RzUCx)

reverse the array

```
f=fliplr(a)
```

take first difference of `f`

```
d = diff(f);
```

find position of where the next element is less than the previous element

```
p=find([1,diff(f)<0,numel(a)])
```

first difference of the positions returns length of each sub array

```
len=diff(p)
```

use length of each sub array in `mat2cell` to split the array to nested list of arrays

```
nest = mat2cell(f,1,len);
```

reverse the nested list

```
rev_nest = fliplr(nest)
```

flatten the nested list

```
[rev_nest{:}]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 41 bytes

```r
ave(x,diffinv(diff(x<-scan())>0),FUN=rev)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7EsVaNCJyUzLS0zr0wDRGtU2OgWJyfmaWhq2hlo6riF@tkWpZZp/jdVMFIwVzBTMFEwVDD@DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
{,/|'x@=+\>':x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#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)

Chunks the input on indices where the value is greater than the previous value, reversing each chunk and concatenating back into a single array.

- `>':x` check whether each element is larger than the prior element
- `=+\` group the cumulative sum of this; elements in each run of equal or decreasing values get assigned their own index in the resulting dictionary
- `x@` index back into the original input to retrieve the original values
- `|'` reverse each chunk
- `,/` flatten the chunks back into a single array

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

*Completely and utterly outgolfed [by Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218911/95126) while I was typing in my answer...!*

```
ṁ↔CẊ-Θ:W<¹L¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9odXNr///huYHihpRD4bqKLc6YOlc8wrlMwrn///9bNSwyLDcsNiw0LDEsM10)

```
ṁ              # map this function:
 ↔             # reverse
               # across all the elements of:
  C            # cut the input into sublists given by
   Ẋ-          # differences between elements of
       W<¹     # list of indices of the input that are less than their successor
     Θ:   L¹   # prepended with zero and appended with the length of the input
```

Comment: Let me introduce you to `ġ`roupby :) https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218911/62393

Comment: @Leo - I pressed 'submit', only to find your answer staring back at me!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 6 bytes

```
ᵃ>ṁƒVf
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLhtYM+4bmBxpJWZiIsIiIsIlsxLCAzLCAyLCAyXSAiLCIzLjQuMSJd)

a weird quirk of "partition after truthy indices" means it matches lengths so it will never include the last value when getting booleans from comparing the overlapping pairs. By appending the reversed list we can always have a partition such that the last values are kept

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 15 bytes

```
s_McQf<@QtT@QTU
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s_McQf%3C%40QtT%40QTU&input=%5B5%2C+2%2C+7%2C+6%2C+4%2C+1%2C+3%5D&debug=0).

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 59 bytes

```
{map |+«*.[0].reverse,m/:s([(\-?\d+)<?{[>=] $0}>] +)+/[0]}
```

Regex-based solution.
Because this is <s>Sparta</s> Perl!!

- `m/  /`: Stringify the input array, and match a regex against it.
- `(\-? \d+)`: Match a number, and capture it as `$0`.
- `<?{ [>=] $0 }>`: Zero-width assertion that only matches if all `$0` captured so far in the current sub-match are in non-ascending order.
- `([  ] +)+`: Repeat the last two steps as often as possible, otherwise start a new sub-match.
- `map   ,   [0]`: Iterate over the sub-matches.
- `|+«*.[0].reverse`: For each one, take the list of values matched by `$0`, reverse it, coerce the values to numbers (`+«`), and slip them into the outer list (`|`).

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 63 bytes

```
sub f(\a){flat $_,f a[+$_..*]with first {[<=] $_},:end,[\R,] a}
```

Recursive list processing solution.
More laborious than I had hoped.
Even though the language has lots of convenient built-ins, there seem to be none for list partitioning (e.g. like Ruby's `slice_when` or Haskell's `takeWhile`).

Answer (score 0):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), noncompeting, 34 bytes

Still constantly developing this language.

```
{e.b:e b last<}chunkby$revmap flat
```

Argument lies on TOS. [Try it here!](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/stacked/stacked.html)

`chunkby` takes a function and collects arrays of contiguous data that satisfy the function. The function then is:

```
{e.b:e b last<}
{e.b:         }  function with arguments [e, <unused>, b]--the element, <the index>, and the
                 chunk being built
     e       <   check if e is less than
       b last    the last element of b
```

This gives a strictly decreasing array.

`$revmap` is basically `[rev]map` and reverses each item.

`flat` finally flattens the array.

---

Some fun for actually sorting the array:

```
[{e.b:e b last<}chunkby$revmap flat] @:sortstep
[$sortstep periodloop] @:sort

10:> @arr
arr out
arr shuf @arr
arr out
arr sort out
```

This outputs (for example):

```
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
(4 5 1 0 6 7 2 8 9 3)
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <s>151</s> 139 Bytes

*Saved 12 Bytes thanks to @Flp.Tkc!*

Nowhere near @Flp.Tkc, let alone...

```
def s(l):
 r=[];i=j=0
 while j<len(l)-1:
  if l[j+1]>l[j]:r+=l[i:j+1][::-1],;i=j+1
  j+=1
 r+=l[i:j+1][::-1],;return[i for s in r for i in s]
```

Comment: Instead of using append, use `+= data,` the trailing comma implicitly constructs a tuple, which is then concatenated with the list, adding the data as the last element in the list. In this context, do `r+=l[i:j+1][::-1],`

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 74 bytes

```
b=[];c=[];a+=9e9,
for i in a[:-1]:
 b=[a.pop(0)]+b
 if b[0]<a[0]:c+=b;b=[]
```

Input in `a`, output in `c`

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 191 Bytes

```
a=[int(i)for i in input().split()]
while a!=sorted(a):
 b=[[]]
 for i,j in enumerate(a):
  if a[i-1]<j:b+=[[j]]
  else:b[-1]+=[j]
 a=[]
 for l in[k[::-1]for k in b]:a+=[k for k in l]
print(a)
```

I'm not sure if using the `sorted` function to check is allowed here, but I couldn't think of a good reason against it, and it brought down my byte count by ~30 Bytes.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 105 bytes

```
#(filter number?(mapcat reverse(partition-by not(mapcat(fn[[a b]][a(< b a)])(partition 2 1(conj % 1))))))
```

Partitions into pairs on consecutive numbers, puts `true` or `false` between them, partitions on `not` to `true` and numbers become `false` and `false` `true`, reverses partitions and keeps numerical values.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 54 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.map((t,i)=>z.splice(q=t<=x[i-1]?q:i,0,t),z=[])&&z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPbjoIwEH33K3hSutsitOBl3bofYshaXTRsUFCJMcZ/Z6fTWmviPgA9Z86cuQC/6qxO62PZtGxf/xTdRnYXOb9EO9WEYUtLIufX6NRU5boID7L9lJdFyZL86/BR0pi2hF7lIif9/rWbLXuLJA/YPIAHHGlwR/qEBHcEB4L7CksIx@koYKvTJyf1ae7T3NFeaUMLQ/sJCZazwRduws/kflC4ah7w@zAdAohpkNGAcZGaeIxmGkPASezdl8R2jN6jGUx57s@6ZHiyU7yWmPms8F@JcKqnl@AXShBw3yVDnJqhDRjTYITU481xFJr0ESq0nOF64ALMgGYQZXpFNgvjY6u5x4XW6NWk6AlwAs4ZmuqaU7g47lAPMMF6iV6n/QpAlmgKBFNTRpjmUnRK0Uj7xcZIG3LjMrFOxmxqTNBsnPeW0bFoKgW/yjCM3oh21s/hdkeD8JsquoLfaV3vT3VVRFW9DZUszqoKFaHBxt2lIVfkfTC43VaEzLo/)

Recurseless win

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=reduce -ap`, 45 bytes

```perl
$_=reduce{$a<$b&&(print$a,$")&&$b||"$b $a"}@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rYoNaU0ObVaJdFGJUlNTaOgKDOvRCVRR0VJU01NJammRkklSUElUanWwe3/f1MFIwVzBTMFEwVDBWMFw3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA2AtE9mcYmVVWhJZg7U4P@6iQUA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ò< cw
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8jwgY3c&input=WzUsIDIsIDcsIDYsIDQsIDEsIDNdIC1R)

```
ò      Partition between elements A, B where the following is true:
 <       A < B
   c   Flatten after mapping each list to:
    w    it reversed
```

Comment: Replace `m` with `c` to get the correct output.

Comment: @Shaggy Forgot about that, nice idea

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 172 bytes

```go
func(s[]int)(o[]int){if len(s)<2{return s}
a:=[]int{s[0]}
for _,e:=range s[1:]{if a[0]<e{o,a=append(o,a...),[]int{e}}else{a=append([]int{e},a...)}}
o=append(o,a...)
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVRNq5tAFN10Nb_iVggojBI1efngWSj0bUtps0tCkXR8SBO1Ogkt4i_pJhTern_olf6Y3rljrE4C7cKvc84993iV-_3HY35-9ot49zl-FHCI04ylhyIvpWclB2l1D9U-3YnKYuwUl5BET0eZuPPnn8kx29nVeptm0rFzfa3TBPYisyvnPqhLIY9lBlXD4mVEfF2tx9uGJXkJH7lYRmWcYedq7S-3qjJG9l7UOY-juChE9snGW8_zHK6rRdOIfSXqjr7AWtU0LDcKmc7Q6My_XvyW3woBK6hkedxJqNOs4OJrAWTUMKbeiSZhO1AzKSpZwTJCelWzWnfzGw6Xu4Z3KIceoR4GXNDngh4XGHUGF_ZppUXIqFZI3-CWIjAUZgIz_FARaoVh41M6Q3e73bXuEqOnC6-S9UAj_vAdERxzmHJwg3DSScfURUHIXanbs6Eet7MYfjuKQS5Xr2V4Twlp5_BPtR5WW_M_6rArMP-JW0l8AgPDe0rQZDhBDc443BE1-KcCqtFmdyTqV7o0djwQd5F2UeWquf81IMmslV0koZL15zyhNgjPsdmU-qgkCzwC-jDqTecUwVffqP0pUeYrCAWLrmOoI0_IbEJeynKsvZRnoI3mrZn2W2gf8pupbLgQ3pVouM9sK4oi-LB6_X4FeGc57Q6TajvoLaaXRc3iHYGJLT3cLg7Dvfby4csx3tvIcOnhusHdAmSc2NboBNGrTQYwOuHZHp2cTbbJLA5UzkEVQVvVYKJBIHh4-wbaQKxdcuezvv4B)

#### Explanation

```go
func(s[]int)(o[]int){
if len(s)<2{return s}            // return the original if it's 1 element or smaller
a:=[]int{s[0]}                   // seed with the first element
for _,e:=range s[1:]{            // for each element of the tail...
 if a[0]<e{                      // if the previous element was smaller than the current...
  o,a=append(o,a...),[]int{e}    // append to the output, and reset
 }else{a=append([]int{e},a...)}} // otherwise push to the front
o=append(o,a...)                 // append the remainder to the output
return}                          // return
```