# Discord large text generator

Tags: code-golf, string

**Input:**

The input will be a string of any characters.

**Output:**

the output will be an emojified (discord emojis) version of the input string. The way it will work is as so:

**Letters:** a-z (case insensitive) will become ':regional_indicator_**lowercase letter here**:'

e.g 'A' will become ':regional_indicator_a:'

**Digits:** any digits (0-9) will become the word version of the digit like so ':**digit**:'

e.g '0' will become ':zero:'

**Whitespace:** any whitespace character that's matched with the regex: /\s/ will become ':white_large_square:'

e.g ' ' will become ':white_large_square:'

**Important notes:**

- The ':' surrounding the emoji's are necessary or else it won't display correctly in discord.
- Each emoji needs to be separated by 1 space or else it won't display correctly in discord.
- Trailing whitespace is allowed in the final output.
- Any other characters that it comes across should not be in the final output and will be ignored.

**Examples:**

**#1:** Input:

```
this is a test string 0123456789
```

output:

```
:regional_indicator_t: :regional_indicator_h: :regional_indicator_i: :regional_indicator_s: :white_large_square: :regional_indicator_i: :regional_indicator_s: :white_large_square: :regional_indicator_a: :white_large_square: :regional_indicator_t: :regional_indicator_e: :regional_indicator_s: :regional_indicator_t: :white_large_square: :regional_indicator_s: :regional_indicator_t: :regional_indicator_r: :regional_indicator_i: :regional_indicator_n: :regional_indicator_g: :white_large_square: :zero: :one: :two: :three: :four: :five: :six: :seven: :eight: :nine:
```

**#2:** input:

```
!?#$YAY 1234
```

output:

```
:regional_indicator_y: :regional_indicator_a: :regional_indicator_y: :white_large_square: :one: :two: :three: :four:
```

**#3:** input:

```
lots         of         spaces
```

output:

```
:regional_indicator_l: :regional_indicator_o: :regional_indicator_t: :regional_indicator_s: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :regional_indicator_o: :regional_indicator_f: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :white_large_square: :regional_indicator_s: :regional_indicator_p: :regional_indicator_a: :regional_indicator_c: :regional_indicator_e: :regional_indicator_s:
```

Examples as shown in discord:

[image: discord examples]

**This is codegolf so the shortest code wins!**

Comment: Yes, it should include all whitespace characters. I've added an example if you need a reference :)

Comment: Please include the test cases as rendered by Discord :-)

Comment: What should tab and newline be replaced with?

Comment: newline should also be the ':white_large_square:', i've editted the post to include all types of whitespace for that ':white_large_square:' :P

Comment: What happens when you input uppercase letters? does it become `:regional_indicator_UPPERCASE:` or `:regional_indicator_uppercase:` ?

Comment: I'll make that clearer in the original post but it should convert it to lowercase like in example #2

Comment: @eniallator You should wait a few days before accepting an answer. Accepting too early discourages new answers.

Comment: Ah thnx. Not rly in the hang of code golf things - still learning :)

Comment: Already have a python3 program to do just this haha, see if i can golf it

Comment: Is the input **one argument** or **multiples**?

Comment: just the one string :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 75 bytes

```
žK… 	
©«Ãlvyaiy’‹¬_Âì_ÿ’}ydiy“¡×€µ‚•„í†ìˆÈŒšï¿Ÿ¯¥Š“#è}®yåi’„¸_…Æ_ï©’}…:ÿ:ðJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390n/ejhmUKnFyHVh5afbg5p6wyMbPyUcPMRw07D62JP9x0GEjsB/JrK1NA4nMOLTw8/VHTmkNbHzXMetSw6FHDvMNrHzUsOLzmdNvhjqOTji48vP7Q/qM7Dq0/tPToAqB65cMrag@tqzy8NBNs6LxDO@KB9h1uiweqWwkyF8izOrzf6vAGr///Fe2VVSIdKxUMjYxNAA)

**Explanation**

```
žK…<space><tab><newline>©«Ã   # remove any character that isn't in [A-Za-z0-9<whitespace>]
lv                            # loop over each character converted to lowercase
yai                           # if it is a letter
   y’‹¬_Âì_ÿ’}                # interpolate into string "regional_indicator_<letter>"
ydi                           # if it is a digit
   y“¡×€µ‚•„í†ìˆÈŒšï¿Ÿ¯¥Š“#è} # extract it from a list of digits as words
®yåi                          # if it is whitespace
    ’„¸_…Æ_ï©’}               # push the string "large_white_square"
…:ÿ:                          # interpolate in string ":<emoji>:" 
    ð                         # push a space
     J                        # join stack to one string
```

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, <s>275</s> <s>268</s> 267 bytes

```
d=['']*256
d[48:58]='zero one two three four five six seven eight nine'.split()
d[9]=d[10]=d[32]='white_large_square'
d[65:90]=d[97:122]=map(lambda c:'regional_indicator_'+chr(c),range(97,122))
print' '.join((':%s:'%d[ord(c)])*(d[ord(c)]!='')for c in input()).strip()
```

It creates a large list of strings, iterates through the input string's characters and gets the string from the list using the character's `ord` value.
Works for ascii characters only. Replaces space, tab and newline only; any other whitespace will be discarded.

It did leave whitespaces in front so I had to strip it in the end.

I also tried doing it with regex, turned out to be longer (286 bytes):

```
import re
print re.sub('([ \t\n])|([a-z])|(\d)',lambda m:':'+['white_large_square','regional_indicator_'+m.group(m.lastindex),'zero one two three four five six seven eight nine'.split()[(ord(m.group(m.lastindex))-68)%10]][m.lastindex-1]+': ',re.sub('[^a-z0-9 \t\n]','',input().lower()))
```

Comment: @mbomb007 seems to miss the first character

Comment: How could I replace `raw_input` to `input`? The program will fail when you input numbers or anything for that matter.

Comment: Ah alright, I see now.

Comment: Okay, I made the changes, now it works for like in example #2.

Comment: You can also replace the [`map/lambda` for a list comprehension](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#jdDNasMwDADge59CowfZbQhrt/4kkPvewYTgxWqikdqZ47ZjL9@5gwW6slEwBgnpk9DZFAqxnC1X64lRz9t8tS0L/CTvwFmCcHIQWk8EO3fwsOMjwcAfMNCRLBA3bQDLljAd@o6DkBHJysKoxePlf1pG7NRyoKrTvqFqeD9oTziZGrVe5dl3UbbJF8tYuNe96PT@1Wioc/TUsLO6q9garnVwvsJ53XpRy8Rr25DINknsk5eRN5b6r3/nPNTAFq6ccjLtPduAgOmbYyuu9lGY49wo500EynmMkng2NWaKIoYJ2/4QjyBlOgTPfTzHL/MuZtzvhxu1a0zcYHImxvghUvJP6nzG8MIDxLeAS842aZriFw "Python 2 – TIO Nexus") in the last lines

Comment: @Rod You are right, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't run for me: https://pastebin.com/6rCv6e0G (weird spacing issue is just an issue of copy/paste from terminal)

Comment: Without weird spacing from copy/paste: https://pastebin.com/hyfD6qMB

Comment: You can replace `':'+d[ord(c)]+':'` with `':%s:'%d[ord(c)]` to save 1 byte.

Answer (score 4):

### [C#](http://csharppad.com/gist/c6123ab5a87e52f51d562a2c69cfdac3), <s>296</s> 273 bytes

---

#### Data

- **Input** `String` `i` The string to be converted
- **Output** `String` The input converted

---

#### Golfed

```cs
(string i)=>{var o="";foreach(var c in i){var k=c|32;var t=k>96&&k<123?"regional_indicator_"+(char)k:char.IsWhiteSpace(c)?"white_large_square":c>47&&c<58?new[]{"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"}[c-48]:"";o+=t!=""?$":{t}: ":t;}return o;};
```

---

#### Ungolfed

```cs
( string i ) => {
   var o = "";
   
   foreach( var c in i ) {
      var k = c | 32;
      var t = k > 96 && k < 123
         ? "regional_indicator_" + (char) k
         : char.IsWhiteSpace( c )
            ? "white_large_square"
            : c > 47 && c < 58
               ? new[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" }[ c - 48 ]
               : "";
               
      o += t != ""
         ? $":{ t }: "
         : t;
   }
   
   return o;
};
```

---

#### Ungolfed readable

```cs
// Receives a string to be converted
( string i ) => {

   // Initializes a var to store the output
   var o = "";
   
   // Cycle through each char in the string
   foreach( var c in i ) {
      // Creates a temp int to check for 'a' - 'z'
      var k = c | 32;
      
      // Creates a temp string that checks if the char is a lowercase letter
      var t = k > 96 && k < 123
         // If so, "builds" a Discord letter
         ? "regional_indicator_" + (char) k
         
         // Otherwise, checks if the char is a whitespace
         : char.IsWhiteSpace( c )
            // If so, "builds" a Discord white square
            ? "white_large_square"
            
            // Otherwise, checks if the char is a digit
            : c > 47 && c < 58
               // If so, gets the digit name
               ? new[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" }[ c - 48 ]
               
               // Otherwise, builds nothing
               : "";
               
      // Checks if the temp string is empty or not
      o += t != ""
         // If so, format it properly -- capsulate with ':' and add a space at the end
         ? $":{ t }: "
         
         // Otherwise, add the temp string, it's empty, so won't do anything
         : t;
   }
   
   // Return the converted string
   return o;
};
```

---

#### Full code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Namespace {
   class Program {
      static void Main( String[] args ) {
         Func<String, String> f = ( string i ) => {
            var o = "";
            
            foreach( var c in i ) {
               var k = c | 32;
               var t = k > 96 && k < 123
                  ? "regional_indicator_" + (char) k
                  : char.IsWhiteSpace( c )
                     ? "white_large_square"
                     : c > 47 && c < 58
                        ? new[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" }[ c - 48 ]
                        : "";
                        
               o += t != ""
                  ? $":{ t }: "
                  : t;
            }
            
            return o;
         };
         
         List<String>
            testCases = new List<String>() {
               "this is a test string 0123456789",
               "!?#$YAY 1234",
               "lots         of         spaces",
            };
         
         foreach( String testCase in testCases ) {
            Console.WriteLine( $" Input: {testCase}\nOutput: {f( testCase )}\n" );
         }

         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

---

#### Releases

- **v1.1** - `-23 bytes` - Implemented [pinkfloydx33](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122427/discord-large-text-generator/122490?noredirect=1#comment300610_122490) suggestions.
- **v1.0** - `296 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

#### Notes

- None

Comment: Can you do bitwise fiddling on the sixth bit to convert to/from lowercase? Not sure if it would help in this scenario as I'm being too lazy to check. You shouldn't  need `new string[] {..} ` but rather just `new[] {..} ` unless I'm missing something

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 the bitwise trick is nice to be implemented, but would increase the byte count -- that, or I don't know how to do it.

Comment: `c|32` is what I was referring to but like I said I didn't check its implications as far as the problem statement or the overall byte count.. That aside you should still be able to recover some bytes by using implicit array typing and replacing `new string[]` with just `new[]`

Comment: I was trying to do it with the `&`, never crossed my mind using the `|`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 142 bytes

```
T`w	¶p`_dll%%%_
.
:$&: 
[a-z]
regional_indicator_$&
%
white_large_square
0
zero
1
one
2
two
3
three
4
four
5
five
6
six
7
seven
8
eight
9
nine
```

Really wish there was an easier way to replace the digits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#BcFLDoIwFAXQsXcVGCkzjfz8MDHuwQkxpjTygJc0rZYChoW5ADeG5yy3alr9vq9K1loLISR2KMKoCHBX2/kBRy1bo7RkU/NTeetkGEFg6tiT1Mq1JPv3oBxhj5mcRQxrCAn8ZJHCd44IGRo7OORoeCQc0PMHR/Q0ksEJxG3ncYZhQ8uyvmzC8loGcZJmfw)

#### Explanation

```
T`w ¶p`_dll%%%_
```

(Note the tab before the `¶`) This is a transliteration stage with changes all letters to lowercase, all whitespace to `%`, and deletes every other character.

```
.
:$&:
```

Next, every character gets wrapped in colons and followed by a space.

```
[a-z]
regional_indicator_$&
```

Next, letters are replaced with regional indicators.

```
%
white_large_square
```

And `%`, which were previously whitespace, are replaced with `white_large_square`.

```
0
zero
1
one
.......
```

And finally, the digits are replaced with their respective emojis.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 184 bytes

```ruby
->x{[x.chars.map{|c|[?:,': ']*(c==$;?'white_large_square':c=~/\d/?%w[zero one two three four five six seven eight nine][c.to_i]:c=~/[A-Z]/i?'regional_indicator_%s'%c.downcase: 0)}]*''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#TYz9SsNAEMT/9ylWbDgtNqnfGomhj1HPIxyXTbIQ7@LtpQm29dVjFSoOAzMMP0Zn0@Jl3MoxNo32HL/rbrszO5mnlyIFoebnJstmz7kYGgpYtNrXWPBHrz2K1GRfyVuZ5NEgP9E7cBYhDA5C4xGhcr2HijYITCMwbtACUt0EsGRRSRMHV5D6fZGrxatKKBcea3JWtwXZkowOzhcRi8jEpRus0YwpLC/2ai7Efur6wKClOM3PZuvVGq6ub26FOjnOoSGGgzUE5AAcPNkalj/U3f3D49M/tHWHPMpVf5U7bZCFmr4B)

Comment: Consider making this a full program so you can use the `-p` flag and `gsub` instead of `x.chars.map`. [Tips source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5050/52194)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP>=7.0, 202 Bytes

```php
for(;a&$c=$argn[$i++];)echo($e=[0,"",ctype_alpha($c)=>regional_indicator_.lcfirst($c),ctype_space($c)=>white_large_square,ctype_digit($c)=>strtolower(substr(IntlChar::charName("$c"),6))][1])?":$e: ":"";
```

It exists no Online Interpreter which contains [IntlChar::charName](http://php.net/manual/de/intlchar.charname.php)

### PHP, 211 Bytes

is the nearest way to solve this without [IntlChar::charName](http://php.net/manual/de/intlchar.charname.php)

```
for(;a&$c=$argn[$i++];)echo($e=[0,"",ctype_alpha($c)=>regional_indicator_.lcfirst($c),ctype_space($c)=>white_large_square,ctype_digit($c)=>[zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine][$c]][1])?":$e: ":"";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#LY2xTsMwFEX3fkUxFk3UB6LAFBMihDqwwMJSRZFluS/xkyLbvLgtMPDXzCHQrveeo3NfRRdnyBxYM8bAiXyXfa/1y@vb89M6VzNpuPPl4qw6l5vHzXx1c3u3UGMbOFPmQtry/68lLZeNytG6kEks62sQAmz6jKhNH53JpM3LB8aOgje9Jr8la9IUveptSzykP@AkDNFYPAoHRwl1PyWm@X1nGE/MljpKR6b@Qg4QPEI6BEiOEaENO4aW9ggDfcCAe/SA1LkEnjw2tbRNU6@avBKFxGIuCiHUOP74cGmNdfgL)

## PHP>=7.0, 220 Bytes

Regex Based

```
<?=preg_replace_callback("#(\pL)|(\d)|(\s)|.#",function($t){$r=!$t[1]?!$t[2]?!$t[3]?"":white_large_square:strtolower(substr(IntlChar::charName("$t[2]"),6)):regional_indicator_.lcfirst($t[1]);return$r?":$r: ":"";},$argn);
```

It exists no Online Interpreter which contains [IntlChar::charName](http://php.net/manual/de/intlchar.charname.php)

### PHP, 229 Bytes

is the nearest way to solve this without [IntlChar::charName](http://php.net/manual/de/intlchar.charname.php)

```
<?=preg_replace_callback("#(\pL)|(\d)|(\s)|.#",function($t){$r=!$t[1]?!$t[2]?!$t[3]?"":white_large_square:[zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine][$t[2]]:regional_indicator_.lcfirst($t[1]);return$r?":$r: ":"";},$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#JY9PT4MwGMbvfIqtNFlJ6pJtnmDYGLODidGLl4URUrsXaGxafCmb0em39swAL8/v9PzbiqZuAkB0WCA0Dr22FfvdFc8vr48PuygJqMTKpou5COn@fj9brTe3iyQQd/1WpA1CNdqMVFAoacybVO@MhOzQPEUXdjiO0kaXZUh42VnltbOM@uibYjqnPlvlYsT6H5tcEBKfa@2hMEMrFO1HJxHi7AvQcWeB@7PjvkYAXroOealPwFv9yVs4geWgq9pzqy3k2RSbx8PAoVOaQtujVtIPN5dGlRpbz6YBUYLgO7QUBYkpxjMSE5L88Ol2lPT9n3U3Sqoarg)

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 141 bytes

```
Óá/:regional_indicator_&:
Óä/½':'.split('zero one two three four five six seven eight nine')[submatch(0)].':'
Óó/:white_large_square:
Ó::/: :
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#FY1LDoIwFAD3nuKtLGws/rVXMaap@KAvwVbbBxiv4QlMvIFrN3IwhGR2k8z03bN7SRWwJO9MpcmdKTfsg56qyeDe8vcVSszitSJOxAODB@8QuPXANiBC4esABTUIke4QsUEHSKVlcORQpIdYny6Gc5tk6XE2tMbsR6rWEqOuTChRx1ttAo5DpaQC1fdsKcKAAcbIEDmQKyGbL5ar9Wa72/8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>212</s> 205 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join('/'<c<':'and':'+'zero one two three four five six seven eight nine'.split()[int(c)]+': 'or'`'<c<'{'and':regional_indicator_'+c+': 'or':white_large_square: '*(c in' 	\n')for c in s.lower())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#NU7LSsRAEDzvX7Qo9IyBiI9TWBE/Y3EljklP0jJ2x57JRvTj16zipaAeVFW83x9TeH/tA@QGsX5TFodXuO222GCQfsUKv8gUVAjKolBGI4Kos0HkA0HmT8h0IAHiYSwgLIR1nhIX559Yiuv8c4UNoBq@/DZ//zUbDawSUsvScxeKWotV9x9tlpELtSnYQG3@mIPRaly6DlgQNntBH9XgRCHXSRcy5/1xstNkdCzTvB5YlbOH84vd424D1ze3dz8)

Comment: Nice, you beat me! This also works in Python 2!

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>197</s> 199 bytes

Fixed underscores not being handled properly thanks to @Neil.

```js
s=>s.toLowerCase().replace(/_|(\d)|(\w)|(\s)|./g,(c,d,a,w)=>a||d||w?`:${a?"regional_indicator_"+c:d?"zero one two three four five six seven eight nine".split` `[c]:"white_large_square"}: `:"").trim()
```

### Cleaned up

```js
s => s.toLowerCase().replace( /_|(\d)|(\w)|(\s)|./g, (c, d, a, w) => {
    if(a || d || w) {
        let out;
        if (a) out = "regional_indicator_" + c;
        else if (d) out = "zero one two three four five six seven eight nine".split(" ")[c];
        else out = "white_large_square";
        return `:${out}: `;
    }
    else {
        return "";
    }
}).trim()
```

### Test Snippet

```js
f=
s=>s.toLowerCase().replace(/_|(\d)|(\w)|(\s)|./g,(c,d,a,w)=>a||d||w?`:${a?"regional_indicator_"+c:d?"zero one two three four five six seven eight nine".split` `[c]:"white_large_square"}: `:"").trim()
```

```html
<input id="I" type="text" size="50" oninput="O.innerHTML=f(I.value)">
<pre id="O" style="width:90vw;white-space:pre-wrap">
```

Comment: Nice but doesn't work for `_`. Hopefully the fix won't cost more than a couple of bytes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do `/_|([\d\w\s])|./g` as your regex.

Comment: I split it into three separate groups so that in the replace function, I have `d`, `a`, and `w` for the three groups. Then I could just check which of those parameters existed to determine digit vs letter vs whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, <s>200</s> 197 Bytes

-3 because the `[A-Za-z]` regex isn't needed in the default case-insensitive regex matches.

```
$a=switch -R ([char[]]"$args"){
"[0-9]"{(-split'zero one two three four five six seven eight nine')["$_"]}
"[a-z]"{"regional_indicator_"+"$_"|% *l*r}
"\s"{"white_large_square"}};":$($a-join': :'):"
```

Would like to find:

a way around using `$a` - wrapping a switch statement in brackets causes it to not work at all for some reason, and any other method is longer than just using a variable.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#Fc1BTsMwEEDRPacYjYySFFliS1AXvQEqrAiRZYVpPMiy07HTQEvOHsz@6f9N2X1aOA8O9BHqbnBWur5HxWGaMza3O@we9VOPt1qnyXOuriQRYiDIS4TshAhOcRY48YUg8TckulAA4tFlCByoajpUBvu1pA763eprqaHQyDFYbzh88mBzFIMP/@73HnZ@J0V/pOIWx5mMtzKSSefZCuG6PmOramX1V@RQtdBWTYvb9lrGYj28UJw8wUEI3n4mDuMf) - input whatever you want and get the result easily.

[image: Several People Are Typing]