# ASCII Meme Arrow Generator

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

## Specifications

Given a number `n`, output an ASCII "meme arrow" (greater-than symbol, `>`) of size `n`.

`n` will always be a positive integer, greater than 0.

### Examples

`n = 2`

```
\
 \
 /
/
```

`n = 5`

```
\
 \
  \
   \
    \
    /
   /
  /
 /
/
```

## Sample code

Here is a sample program, written in Crystal, that returns the correct results. Run it as `./arrow 10`.

`arrow.cr`:

```ruby
def f(i)
        i.times { |j|
                j.times { print ' ' }
                puts "\\"
        }
        i.times { |j|
                (i-j-1).times { print ' ' }
                puts '/'
        }
end

f(ARGV[0].to_i)
```

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). The shortest answer wins. However, I will not select an answer, because the shortest answer may change over time.
- Standard loopholes are not allowed.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a duplicate (that is, did you sandbox this)? I think this is likely to be, but it's slightly nearly impossible to search for.

Comment: @someone didn't think about the sandbox, but i did search around a bit and didn't find something similar. i should remember to do that next time

Comment: Can `n` be zero?

Comment: @xnor No. I'll add it to the specification.

Comment: I think it's pretty silly to call this common symbol a "meme arrow". They're obviously comedy chevrons.

Comment: @Christian They're actually amusing angles

Comment: @dkudriavtsev Officially, it's a playful pointer.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl I thought they were interesting increases

Comment: @dkudravtsev Not silly signage?

Comment: > Is me
> Challenge about meme arrows exists
> Writes comment using meme arrows because it's ironic
> No one reads comment
> Frick

Comment: @lyxal thanks to your comment i know what this challenge is about lol

Comment: Ok to output with extra whitespace on each line that doesn't effect how the image looks?

Answer (score 12):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
＼═
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNDJXUyNTUw,i=NQ__,v=8)

Comment: Code itself is like smile actually.

Answer (score 10):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 56 bytes

```c
f(n,i){for(i=-n;n;printf("%*c\n",i?++i+n:n--,i?92:47));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI08nU7M6Lb9II9NWN886z7qgKDOvJE1DSVUrOSZPSSfTXls7UzvPKk9XF8i2NLIyMdfUtK79n5uYmaehWc2VpmGkaQ0kTYFk7X8A)

```c
f(n,i){for(i=-n;i;printf("%*c\n",  ++i+n    ,  92   ));     //first print descending '\'s
       for(    ;n;printf("%*c\n",        n--,     47));}    // then print returning  '/'s
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,p='':n*'?'and p+'\\\n'+f(n-1,p+' ')+p+'/\n'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIU@nwFZd3SpPS91ePTEvRaFAWz0mJiZPXTtNI0/XUAfIVVDX1AZS@kDB/wVFmXklCmkamXkFpSUampr/TQE)

Outputs with a trailing newline.

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 66 bytes

```cs
n=>new int[n*2].Select((a,b)=>"".PadLeft(b<n?b:n*2+~b)+"\\/"[b/n])
```

Saved a byte thanks to @someone.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY0xb4MwEIXn8itOnnw1hbZjwO7USq0YKmXIAAw2OSJLySGB02z56/Rapu/u6dN7w/I0LHH9uPJQR0755ztfLzT7cKZ6SXPkk3OjXdk6phuI0fLja1/s6UxD0trnAa1Tqvj2x4bGpEPNb2EnjrkHNKrrStWGkntcq@xnikdItCQtPeARrIPDHBM1kUl7MKB2HSvhtlx8TZG1kigftUf8E@TBKhun@b8jgoWXSlALn@UwBrOHbQKr9Rc)

Comment: `n*2-b-1` -> `n*2+~b`

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 36 bytes

```perl
$\=($q=$"x$_)."\\
$\$q/
"while$_--}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxlZDpdBWRalCJV5TTykmhkslRqVQn0upPCMzJ1UlXle3tvr/f@N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usWAAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
'\3.Λ∊
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPcZY79zsRx1d//@bAgA)

**Explanation**

```
   .Λ    # draw
'\       # the string "\"
         # of length input
  3      # in the south-eastern direction
     ∊   # then vertically mirror it
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>111</s> <s>99</s> <s>77</s> <s>73</s> <s>68</s> <s>64</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

-12 bytes thanks to [Benjamin Urquhart](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84303/benjamin-urquhart), -43 thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) and -2 bytes thanks to [Value Ink](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/value-ink).

```ruby
->i{s=[];puts (0...i).map{|j|s=(p=' '*j)+?/,*s;p+?\\},s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6zutg2Ota6oLSkWEHDQE9PL1NTLzexoLomq6bYVqPAVl1BXStLU9teX0er2LpA2z4mplanuPY/WL26sZU6V1q0cSwXmKsUk2dqpQQUMI39DwA)

Explanation:

```ruby
f=->i{                      # instead of a function, use a lambda
  s=[]                      # needs a helper variable *now*, for scope
  puts(                     # puts takes arbitrary num of args; \n after each
    (0...i).map{|j|         # not from 0 to i but from 0 to i-1 (*three* dots)
      s=(
        p=' '*j             # p will remain in scope inside of .map,
      )
      +?/                   # character literal instead of string
      ,*s                   # essentially appending to the array
      
      p+?\\                 # p is what's returned by .map, not s!
      
    },                      # up until here, 1st arg to display
    s                       # NOW, as the *2nd* arg, s is displayed
  )
}
```

## Alternative (but longer) Solutions

A friend read this answer and then tried to come up with a couple more approaches. Putting them here, too, so that they're not lost to the vast interwebs.

### inject and unshift, 72 bytes

```ruby
->n{puts (0...n).inject([]){|s,i|i=' '*(n-1-i);s.unshift i+?\\;s<<i+?/}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vuqC0pFhBw0BPTy9PUy8zLys1uUQjOlazuqZYJ7Mm01ZdQV1LI0/XUDdT07pYrzSvOCMzrUQhU9s@Jsa62MYGyNCvrf0PNkTd2EqdKy3aOJYLzFWKyTO1UgIKmMb@BwA)

### downto, inject and unshift, 80 bytes

```ruby
->n{puts n.downto(1).map{|i|' '*(i-1)}.inject([]){|s,i|s<<i+?/;s.unshift i+?\\}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vuqC0pFghTy8lvzyvJF/DUFMvN7GguiazRl1BXUsjU9dQs1YvMy8rNblEIzpWs7qmWCezptjGJlPbXt@6WK80rzgjM61EAciNiamt/Q82TN3YSp0rLdo4lgvMVYrJM7VSAgqYxv4HAA)

### intriguing, two non-nested loops, 127 bytes

```ruby
->n{
r=->s,c{s[0..-(c+1)],s[-c..-1]=s[c..-1],s[0..c-1];s};
n.times{|i|puts r[' '*n+?\\,n-i]}
n.times{|i|puts r[' '*n+?/,i+1]}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYqxDsIgFEV3vqLpgsoDJU2XNtQPARaJTRgkhtcOhvLtSHB2O@fcG/fHp6yq8CUkEhVfEFxCfROCnxyTZwuouasmrUL9A2i7qzRjnkkQm389MR3@eO8bdlHTjl4CuxsDgXub/z@u4Jmsh1xap8NEyaoHS5r2JoxTX8Noyxc)

Comment: Can't a lot of that whitespace be removed?

Comment: Yes, 12 bytes in total, thank you! This was the first time I submitted anything to a code golf game...

Comment: Then you may find interesting the [Tips for golfing in Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby), or even the [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages).

Comment: You could replace the inner loops for padding with [`String#rjust`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-rjust) ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/PyU1TSFNI1PTOlOvJDM3tbi6JqumoLSkWD0mRl2vKKu0uEQhS9uwFkNaHyabqZtVa52al/IfJKygZGSlxJWmYaTJBeHG5JmCBUw1/wMA "Ruby – Try It Online")).

Comment: Here I applied some of the tips from the above mentioned 2 collections to reduce it to 57 characters: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6zuthWXd26oLSkWEHDQE9PL1NTLzexoLomq6bYVkm5usBWXUFdK6tWn0tJu9i6QNs@JqZWp7j2P1iDkpGVEldatFEsF4Qbk2cKFjCN/Q8A "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: I've worked my way forward to 64 bytes and feel like I (mostly) understand what you're doing in your 57 bytes version. What I don't get at all yet: why is `?something` equivalent to `'something'`? Also: is it generally considered not-cheating in Code Golf to outsource the `f=` as you've done in your TIO?

Comment: If your string interpolation is at the end of the string AND the variable is a string, you're better off going `..."+s` than `...#{s}"`. Also, Ruby strings can go through multiple lines, so you can replace `\n` with a literal newline. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6zuthWXd26oLSkWEHDQE9PL1NTLzexoLomq6bYVkm5usBWXUFdK6tWn0tJu9i6QNs@JqZWp7j2P1iDupGVOldatFEsF5irFJNnaqUEFDCN/Q8A "Ruby – Try It Online") And yes, it isn't cheating to outsource the `f=` because `->{yourcode}[input]` is also valid code, so technically assigning it to a variable is optional.

Comment: @manatwork already did the `..."+s` and the literal newline things in the version linked to in his last comment. I'm holding back on them until I feel I also understand the `?\\` thing. Thank you for the comment on `f=`, @Value Ink!

Comment: @RainerVerteidiger, looking for this? “There is also a character literal notation to represent single character strings, which syntax is a question mark (?) followed by a single character or escape sequence that corresponds to a single codepoint in the script encoding” — [Literals / Strings](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings).

Comment: Aha! Yes, that's what I'd been looking for, thank you!

Comment: It's now fully down to the 57 bytes version originally by @manatwork, for which I totally don't deserve any credit. Thanks to all of you, this taught me an awful lot about the language I (have to) do my day-to-day chores in, and on top of it, was fun to do! :-D

Comment: [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)'s [splat tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54766) helped reduce it with 1 more character: `->i{s=[];puts (0...i).map{|j|s=(p=' '*j)+?/,*s;p+?\\},s}` — [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6zutg2Ota6oLSkWEHDQE9PL1NTLzexoLomq6bYVqPAVl1BXStLU9teX0er2LpA2z4mplanuPY/WL26sZU6V1q0cSwXmKsUk2dqpQQUMI39DwA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: Took me a while to understand that change, but finally added to the answer now. I like it much better than the previous one with a newline inside of it, as it's back to being a true one-liner.

Still nowhere close to beating-Haskell-territory, unfortunately :-P

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>44</s> 41 bytes

```powershell
filter f{if($_){'\'
--$_|f|%{" $_"}
'/'}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py0zpyS1SCGtOjNNQyVes1o9Rp1LV1clviatRrVaSUElXqmWS11fvbb2v6GenhlQDCRlraCuXvsfAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG), <strike>719</strike> 677 bytes

```
+
+
+
+
+
+         ((((+)+++++)))<
+>======================"
+)++++++)+++++++++++((-[!)
========================#=-
) ![-    <+;)+++)---)++++)<
)=#======"=================
) >)+)+((!
+ "======#
         <))))).(((((((<
 ========">============"
>)+)+((-[!+))        -[!((((((((.)).))))+(-[!)
"========#=============#====================#<
!)                                          <
#==========================================="
                  >(((((.)))>
                  "========<"========
 ![-)).))).(((((((![-    ))+![-((+)+)<((![<
 #================#=========#========"==#="===
 >                                   !  >-!
 "===================================#  "=#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVG7CsMwDNz1FX4sFsbdOlX2j2TKVAp9QP8fXMmvEpzSXIYose90Jz3W9@11X5/XnD2MR3U4hkcvQEQCn@IuDLRb/VXgXFg0QvwBGwOg0kuQTuQvQsUQQpHgZsg3qvpEZV5C7uWcZrft3MLwTSg4uQoCNYymre2mwj45YGfzV2O6E6uIlK9RzNf7NslePAI9JP@DwMbjMDArpO4Y087psE6jAhl@DdhH1bbBgbkqu0eSvzxCO@9vqozUpkinA5k1mw4alDmQ2EoEm/P5Aw)

This was harder than expected...

Answer (score 4):

## C64Mini/C64 BASIC (and other CBM BASIC variants), 52 tokenized BASIC bytes used

```
 0INPUTN:N=N-1:FORI=0TON:PRINTTAB(I)"\":NEXT:FORI=NTO0STEP-1:PRINTTAB(I)"/":NEXT
```

Here is the non-obfuscated version for exaplantion:

```
 0 INPUT N
 1 LET N=N-1
 2 FOR I=0 TO N
 3  PRINT TAB(I);"\"
 4 NEXT I
 5 FOR I=N TO 0 STEP -1
 6  PRINT TAB(I);"/"
 7 NEXT I
```

What ever number is entered into `N` in line zero is reduced by one as the `TAB` command is zero-indexed; The `FOR/NEXT` loops in lines two through to four and five through to seven then output the upper and lower part if the `meme` arrow respectively (represented by a shifted `M` and shifted `N` in graphics mode [source](http://sta.c64.org/cbm64pet.html))

[image: Commodore C64 meme arrow]

Comment: Did you know that in Commodore Basic all keywords can be abbreviated? Here's a link: https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/BASIC_keyword_abbreviation 
For example, `for` can be `fO` (`f` - shoft `o`), `print` is `?`,  etc.

Comment: 52 bytes is misleading in Code Golf, the binaries don't count, just the source code.
It shoulf be something ike this: `0inputn:n=n-1:fOi=0ton:?tA(i)"\":nE:fOi=0ton:?tA(i)"/":nE` - it takes 57 bytes.

Comment: As discussed here -> https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11553/how-should-the-length-of-a-commodore-64-basic-program-be-measured/11574#11574 I count the tokens used as this is more representative of how much of the memory is being used.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this. Is there a decision about this? Even the answer has not been accepted there.

Comment: Well I state tokenized BASIC bytes (rather than number of PETSCII characters) as this is the most consistent way to count the memory used in Commodore BASIC. I have known about keyword abbreviations since I was 8 years old a long time ago.

Comment: Also if you enter a whole listing, however long, with abbreviations, when you list it you will see it non-abbreviated. You only need them to get >80 characters per line in C64 BASIC (or >160 in C128 BASIC)

Comment: My first computer was a C16, I did a lot of assembly on that, too, so no offence, I love Commodore. C16 had Basic 3,5, 80 chars per line, I also had a book with the ROM listings explained, so I exactly knew how the tokenization and listing worked,

Comment: Seeing the fact that the listing contains untokenized text, it makes sense that the "source code" should not be the abbreviated version. But I'm still in doubt whether the number of bytes should be the measure, because that is a compiled code (binaries) - using this principle, Java code should be golfed based on the compiled class size. 
Anyways, this solution is good, upvoted, and I also made my contribution here with Rockstar language.

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 125 bytes

```
++++++++++[->+>+++++++++>+++<<<]>>++>++>,[->[->+<<<.>>]<<<.<.>>>>>[-<+>]<+<]<<[--<<+>>]<<+>>>>>[-[-<+<.>>]<<<<<.>.>>>[->+<]>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBCoBADAMfVLsvKPnI0oMKgggeBN9fk0Xtpcmk6XLN@7nd61Fl/3SH4XdSEZHA0JgY64KsAaklwekeRmBB2N2DTrm9oeKvom4blI8SWfUA)

```
++++++++++[->+>+++++++++>+++<<<]>>++>++>    ; Initialize with " \"
,                                           ; Get input
[->                                         ; loop and decrement n 
    [->+<<<.>>]                             ; output number of spaces, copy n
    <<<.                                    ; output \
    <.                                      ; output newline
    >>>>                                    
    >[-<+>]<+                               ; copy copy of n back to original place 
<]
<<[--<<+>>]<<+>>                            ; change "\" to "/"
>>>                             
[                                           ; second loop for bottom half
 -                                          ; decrement n
 [-<+<.>>]                                  ; output n spaces
 <<<<<.>.                                   ; output \ and newline
 >>>[->+<]>                                 ; copy n back
]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 5 bytes

```
↘Ｎ‖Ｍ↓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMPKJb88LygzPaNER8Ezr6C0xK80Nym1SENT05orKDUtJzW5xDezqCi/CKJS0/r/f9P/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
↘Ｎ
```

Input a number and print a diagonal line of `\`s of that length.

```
‖Ｍ↓
```

Reflect the line vertically.

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL code, 80 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ INT=3

,@z INT=0
x:PRINT
space(@-abs(@-@z-.5))+char(92-@z/@*45)SET
@z+=1IF @z<@*2GOTO x
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1062368/ascii-meme-arrow-generator)**

## T-SQL query, 96 bytes

In order to make this work online i had to make some minor alterations.
Spaces in the beginning of a row doesn't display in the online snippet. So I am using ascii 160 instead. When running in management studio, it is possible to change the settings to show result as text, which would result in the correct spaces in this posted script.

```sql
DECLARE @ INT=3
SELECT space(@-abs(@-number-.5))+char(92-number/@*45)FROM
spt_values WHERE number<@*2and'p'=type
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1062337/ascii-meme-arrow-generator)**

Answer (score 3):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 69 bytes

```
%@!0//[!1A]%[1A[1A84W;]%99W25WM1M;25W;]%[!1A]~[1A[1A84W;]%67W5M;25W;]
```

I am not going to golf this further bcause funny number. Sorry, guys.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%25%40!0%2F%2F%5B!1A%5D%25%5B1A%5B1A84W%3B%5D%2599W25WM1M%3B25W%3B%5D%25%5B!1A%5D%7E%5B1A%5B1A84W%3B%5D%2567W5M%3B25W%3B%5D&input=5)

Comment: +1 for 69!! (15chrs)

Answer (score 2):

## APL(NARS), 40 chars, 80 bytes

```
{f←{⍺,⍨⍵⍴' '}⋄⊃('\'f¨k),('/'f¨⌽k←¯1+⍳⍵)}
```

test:

```
  h←{f←{⍺,⍨⍵⍴' '}⋄⊃('\'f¨k),('/'f¨⌽k←¯1+⍳⍵)}
  h 2
\ 
 \
 /
/ 
  h 5
\    
 \   
  \  
   \ 
    \
    /
   / 
  /  
 /   
/
```

Answer (score 2):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org)'s type system, 87 bytes

```typescript
//@ts-nocheck
type F<N,S="">=N extends[{},...infer N]?`
${S}\\${F<N,`${S} `>}
${S}/`:""
```

[Try it at the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTACBcGcFoDsHsDGALApog1gWAFDgJ4AOqABAGIA8AcgDQDKAvAERMB8DVJqAHuKrABNIAbQDeAXxoA6GQEtYAM1QAnElQC6AfgAGuACSi64gDrGDlWtoNGS21uP2HxwbQC4WuXAWIkAsgHkAVToAUQB9fwA1EIAlMN8QkgZyCmEARhoMrMz1VlwQEkIAQ0g+EjRlUnB4EkhUUkR4ZUrEcAAbfFd84HLwcEJIVxAi6qlCblQAcxUpRoBbYGUAV1hNNIY5gHYABgwAGQAvAA42gUQAcSKAVgAFfCOAFgA3fERIvYAmRDCACToqYqBNpFABG8AA6lR8B9IgBNJ4AKVksLme3wZF8AEEQm0AJIxGKIMjwBQAFVxZARIUxPxC0Aw8AAipjuAAtACOjKWkzIAGF8JjtpjMbggA)

Takes input as a unary number represented by a tuple type N. If I instead took the unary number as a string type of spaces, this becomes **71 bytes:**

```typescript
type F<S,O=''>=S extends` ${infer S}`?F<S,`${S}\\
${O&string}${S}/
`>:O
```

[Try it at the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAZQDQHkC8AiDA+NCoQAewEAdgCYDOABlACQDeAlqQGYQBOUCAvtQPzxk1RrwA6YgLAAoRigBklYBxYBzHqJ4B6GdWwAuFDJmhIUALIoAqggCiAfRQA1WwCV7521DSw4GKAEBODJaWlBgAIZK0AAWnNDAAPZQlBDQAMaJHBwQ6cAANiD6IWExwMBglPqhEUkAdGCEEKqcdZkAtlocAK6k-ACMaO0A7AAMANYAMgBeABz55OkA4hEArAAKILMALABuIOlOkwBM6fYAEggAcpFW+REARokA6lcgx04Amu0AUkyzMQAKgBBABCPzsVgAGqCIudRiBQQhXGDCLYAMLjUEAERgqkSCAitihHGBwIAiqpzMCZEA)

I like the shorter version better because it's tail-recursive and just overall really elegant, but I think the I/O format is a little cheaty.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 8 bytes

```
ɾ\\↳↲øṀ§
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLJvlxcXFzihrPihrLDuOG5gMKnIiwiIiwiNSJd)

```
   ↳     # Right-pad
 \\      # \
ɾ        # To length each of range(1, n+1)
    ↲    # Left-pad each to length n
     øṀ  # Mirror, flipping slashes
       § # Vertical join, transposing and joining by newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>67</s> 65 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

```c
f(n,i){for(i=~n;i++<n;)i&&printf("%*c\n",n-abs(i)+1,"/\\"[i<0]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrNCsIwDADgs3sKKTgS2@IPeOp8EuuhBjICW5TN29gefXGevstHsSUyY9AgOPF7ALkvmsT7RhNKXX8G0S@DOxwpqwsay2sEQX8J7pSze0hzfmKabVv7vogCVlO1Y7hh@nPdmG0l7ko7Wuz6Hw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 32 bytes

```
.+
$* ¶$&$* 
\G.
¶$`\
r`.\G
$'/¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRUvh0DYVNSDFFeOuxwVkJ8RwFSXoxbhzqajrH9r2/78pAA) Explanation:

```
.+
$* ¶$&$*
```

Generate two lines of `n` spaces.

```
\G.
¶$`\
```

Turn the top line into a `\` diagonal.

```
r`.\G
$'/¶
```

Turn the bottom line into a `/` diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>52</s> 49 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [Sriotchilism O'Zaic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/sriotchilism-ozaic).

```hs
unlines.g
g 0=[]
g n="\\":map(' ':)(g$n-1)++["/"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyflfraus4OPo5x7q6O6q4BwQoKCsW8vFlZuYmadgq5CSz6WgUFBaElxS5JOnoKKgZGSlhCqSpmCEpsQUU4kpF1ca0LSY/6V5OZl5qcV66VzpCga20bFAKs9WKSZGySo3sUBDXUHdSlMjXSVP11BTWztaSV8p9v9/AA)

Comment: You can save a byte with `g$n-1` instead of `g(n-1)`.  You also don't need to count the `f=` since `f` never gets referenced.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>85</s> <s>84</s> <s>81</s> <s>80</s> 75 bytes

```python
def a(n):l="for i in range(n):print' '*";exec l+"i+'\\\\'\n"+l+"(n+~i)+'/'"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcgxCoAwDEDRq4Qsac0gCC6KN3EpWjUgaSkVdPHqtf7t/fjkI2hXyuo3cEbtcE64hQQCopCc7v6fMYlmAmpw9Ldf4GQUprlGsyJXGuVXLFNLWJwRjVc21pb@Aw)

Comment: -1 with r-strings: `def a(n):l="for i in range(n):print' '*";exec l+r"i+'\\'\n"+l+"(n+~i)+'/'"`

Comment: @Makonede Leads to a `SyntaxError` unfortunately :(

Comment: Ah, maybe r-strings weren't a thing in Python 2. Oh well.

Comment: They were, but the `\n` can't be in a raw string even in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 50 bytes

```powershell
param($n)0..--$n|%{' '*$_+'\'}
$n..0|%{' '*$_+'/'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlT9NAT09XVyWvRrVaXUFdSyVeWz1GvZZLJU9PzwBJTF@99n8tF5ehnp4ZUFRNJU1BJd5aQR0oCgA)

Will look into making it so it only goes through the range once. Not bad for the no brain method though.

Answer (score 1):

## Twig, 115 bytes

Builds the string backwards, "returning" it in the end.

Uses a macro to generate all the results.

```
{%macro a(N,s="")%}{%for i in N..1%}{%set s=('%'~i~'s
'~s~'%'~i~'s
')|format('\\','/')%}{%endfor%}{{s}}{%endmacro%}
```

This macro has to be in a file, and imported like this:

```
{% import 'macro.twig' as a %}

{{ a.a(<value>) }}
```

You can try it on https://twigfiddle.com/5hzlpz (click on "Show raw result").

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
Xy92*t45-Pvc
```

*1 Byte saved thanks to @LuisMendo*

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab the input as an integer
Xy      % Create an identity matrix this size
92*     % Multiply by 92 (ASCII for '\')
t       % Duplicate the matrix
45-     % Subtract 45 from every element yielding 47 (ASCII for '/') on the diagonal
        % and -45 everywhere else
P       % Vertically flip this matrix
v       % Vertically concatenate the two matrices
c       % Convert to characters (negative numbers are replaced with a space)
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Try it out at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=Xy92%2at45-Pvc&inputs=5&version=20.11.0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 19 bytes

```
VQ+*dN\\)V_Q+*dhN\/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyxQWyvFLyZGMywexMrwi9H//98YAA)

TIL multiplying a string by a negative value multiplies it by its absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>90</s> 83 bytes

```python
lambda n:'\n'.join([' '*i+'\\'for i in range(n)]+[' '*(n+~i)+'/'for i in range(n)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcrBDkExEEbhvaeY3cyokEZsbnKfRC0qlBH@Nk0tRHj1CgsLsf3OKbd2zFj2NIZ@jpftLhIGDuD5KRtkzcRTcxwCp1zJyEA14rAX6MZ9qsA9TR0v/hzaf8zPvDM0MZRrE1UdJlTqWxJjvNuD9Qtiqt2vXg)

-7 bytes thanks to @squid

Comment: [83 bytes](https://tio.run/##bcrBDkExEEbhvaeY3cyokEZsbnKfRC0qlBH@Nk0tRHj1CgsLsf3OKbd2zFj2NIZ@jpftLhIGDuD5KRtkzcRTcxwCp1zJyEA14rAX6MZ9qsA9TR0v/hzaf8zPvDM0MZRrE1UdJlTqWxJjvNuD9Qtiqt2vXg "Python 3 – Try It Online"), but I feel like it can still go down

Comment: I wish [this](https://tio.run/##TcyxCkIxDIXh3afIlsRclCIuF/ok1qGi1YimpdRBRF@94h3U8XwH/nJvp2yrnnzol3jd7SPYUH2NdjyQ8YjBcHHOarRBwLkKhoApV1BQg7qVicnkpSy4/L@4/8aUc4MTtUZq5daImccZlPqRhOYf@kT@Ailzd@s3) was possible.

Comment: [Soon](https://tio.run/##RcpBCgIxDEDRvafoLokVpYgghZ7EzqKi1YimJdSFiF696izG5X/8@mjnIutt1Z5D7Nd02x@SEQ9RYHkpLLgDA3O2ECPkoobN19QHTXI6ohANdjxQ7JvJwmq6jA7U/zH@buEsS0OWem9IRH5mqv4kg4Qnv4AmQCbqbvMB "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")...

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot about that. Maybe you should submit it!

Answer (score 1):

## Rockstar, 133 bytes

Try it online [here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online)!

```
F takes N,S
If N is 0
Give back N

Say S+"\"
Let T be S+" "
Let M be N-1
F taking M,T
Say S+"/"

Listen to X
F taking X,""
```

Since Rockstar is not famous for string operations, it takes relatively lots of code to do it (recursively was even longer).

The size of the arrow is taken as input.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>79</del> <del>63</del> 61 bytes

```php
function f($x,$s=''){if($x)echo"$s\\
",f($x-1,"$s "),"$s/
";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRUKnRUim3V1TWrM0EczdTkjHwlleKYGC4lHZCArqEOkKugpAmi9LmUrGv/p2koqCQWpZdFG8YqaFr//28KAA)

Recursive in PHP.

#### *-12 bytes* by [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/186548/ascii-meme-arrow-generator/187012#comment448006_187012)

Comment: Better count down. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRUKnRUim3V1TWrM0EczdTkjHyVYh2lmBguJR2QiK6hjpJKsYKSpg5IWJ9Lybr2f5qGgkpiUXpZtGGsgqb1//@mAA "PHP – Try It Online").

Comment: @manatwork very very nice!

Answer (score 1):

## [\/\/>](https://github.com/torcado194/worm), 74 bytes

```
jp100o
-84*}!o:?!x1
@+:q:p=?x:o~$:0(pa"\/"q?$~}}:
x2-:p$1-y$:0(?
.{suh?!;2
```

**Explanation:** (lines rotated based on start point)

```c
jp100o                        //setup
:?!x1-84*}!                   //add leading spaces, loop and decrement until 0
~$:0(pa"\/"q?$~}}:@+:q:p=?x:o //add correct slash, go back to loop or switch sides
$:0(?x2-:p$1-y                //flip direction state or continue to print
{suh?!;2.                     //remove extra data and print stack
```

Comment: `\/\/> (pronounced wɜrm)` Thanks, I hate it. (jk, I'm looking forward to giving it a try)

Comment: @JoKing hahaha, gotta wear my inspiration on my sleeve. (thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i="":n and i+"\\\n"+f(n-1,i+" ")+i+"/\n"or""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIU8n01ZJySpPITEvRSFTWykmJiZPSTtNI0/XUAfIVVDS1AZS@kDB/CIlpf8FRZl5JRppGoaamlwwthES2xiJbWigqfkfAA)

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIU8n01ZJySpPS0lBKTEvRSFTWykmJiZPSTtNI0/XUAfIVVDS1AZS@kDB/wVFmXklGmkahpqaXDC2ERLbGIltaKCp@R8A).

Answer (score 1):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 69 bytes

Port of xnor's Python answer.

```erlang
r(0,_)->"";r(I,X)->X++"\\\n"++r(I-1,X++" ")++X++"/\n".
r(I)->r(I,"").
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5z/W/SMNAJ15T105JybpIw1MnAsiM0NZWiomJyVPS1gYK6RrqgAQUlDS1tUEMfaCEHhdQAqgSpENJSVPvf25iZp5GdKymgq6dQma@VVp5UWZJqkaRhqkmUBIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>91</s> 86 bytes

```python
n=range(int(input()))
for i in n:print(' '*i+'\\')
for i in n:print(' '*(n[-1]-i)+'/')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8@2KDEvPVUjM68EiAtKSzQ0NTW50vKLFDIVMvMU8qwKikBS6grqWpna6jEx6jgkNfKidQ1jdTM1tdX11TX//zcCAA)

Edit 1: saved 5 bytes by making n a range instead of integer

Comment: You can golf this a bit if you [port this to Python 2](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDkystv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VSNP06qgKDOvRF1BXStTWz0mRh2fCo083UxdQ01tdX31//@NAA) :) And there are definitely more optimizations you can make!

Comment: @RGS, Thanks! Don't really want to switch to python 2, but here is your port in 77 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8@2KDEvPVUjM6@gtERDU5MrLb9IIVMhM08hz6qgKDOvRF1BXStTWz0mRh2rlEZetK5hrG6mpra6vvr//6YA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: [80 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8@2KDEvPVUjM68EiAtKSzQ0NTW5KmzV1bnS8osUMhUy8xTyrAqKQPLqCupamdrqMTHqmtZAFRCefkyeunYFF0RFheb//0YA)

Comment: Or even [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8K2ylZdnSu1IjVZQ6mgKDOvRKNKWz0GCNQ1rYGS2ur6MTF56toV1lXatuoK6tZKWiA1mXkFpSUampqaXBA9FZr//xsBAA) using `exec`

Comment: [71 even](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8K2ylZdnSu1IjVZQ6mgKDOvRKNKWz1GQV3TGiilra4fE5Onrl1hXaVtq66gbq2kBVKRmVdQWqKhqanJBdFRofn/vxEA "Python 3 – Try It Online") if trailing spaces after \ are acceptable...

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `j`, 95 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 11.875 bytes

```
ƛI\\JøṀ;½fyRṘJ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJqPSIsIiIsIsabSVxcXFxKw7jhuYA7wr1meVLhuZhKIiwiIiwiNCJd)

Bitstring:

```
00001000000011101111110001100110011110111010010010110001001000111000011010000100001110000011111
```

Beats all non-canvas users

Comment: Well it’s 14 SBCS which loses to MATL, and I can’t tell if the 10-byte Stax is using a canvas

Comment: stax has byte packing

Comment: So? That's not so different from vyncode

Answer (score 1):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang), 58 bytes

```
=i=a'(`1=b;space,i~>"\"!+}7,a`2!-=b;space,i~>divide!}7,0,2
```

and just for fun...

## ibe, 118 bytes

```
adadadadadadaddsRafWmreafYmpeafUmtiakqskTagTmwakwafTmwslWssTmQmwaaYafQmwssQmRmqakeskTakrafTmwslWssTmQmraaUagQmwsaQmqme
```

(this is an esolang i made a while ago that i dont plan on releasing)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,s='':n and f(n-1,~-n*' '+'\\\n'+s+~-n*' '+'/\n')or s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIU@n2FZd3SpPITEvRSFNI0/XUKdON09LXUFdWz0mJiZPXbtYGy6gD@Rr5hcpFP8vKMrMKwGqN9TkgjGNEExjTa7/RgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç₧¥╗M'gQ9⌂
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=809e9dbb4d276751397f&i=2%0A5&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 42 bytes (If trailing new line is allowed)

```javascript
n=>(F=s=>n--?s+`\\
`+F(s+" ")+s+`/
`:"")``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k7DzbbY1i5PV9e@WDshJoYrQdtNo1hbSUFJUxsooM@VYKWkpJmQ8N86OT@vOD8nVS8nP10jTcNUU/M/AA)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```javascript
n=>(F=s=>s+`\\
${--n?F(s+" ")+`
`:""}${s}/`)``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k7DzbbY1q5YOyEmhkulWlc3z95No1hbSUFJUzuBK8FKSalWpbq4Vj9BMyHhv3Vyfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqmm5n8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate), 100 bytes

This was quite a fun challenge, but some bugs in the language made it hard to optimize.

```
{@set_ argv.0}{@while_}{@callstr_repeat intoS" ",_}{@setO S,"\\\n",O,S,"/\n"}{@incby-1_}{@/}{@echoO}
```

Basically, cycles throught the values backwards, working the string from the middle out.

---

**How the answer should be**

Due to the bugs, the code wasn't being interpreted properly.

This is how the code would be, if the compiler didn't had any bug (86 bytes):

```
{@forfrom argv.0to0step-1}{@callrepeat intoS" ",_}{@setO S,"\\
",O,S,"/
"}{@/}{@echoO}
```

Oh, well, at least the solution works :x

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 5/Xcode 10.2.1](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 91 bytes

```swift
(0..<n*2).map{String(repeating:" ",count:$0<n ?$0:n*2-$0-1)+($0<n ?"\\":"/")+"\n"}.joined()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY6xDoJAEER7v2KzobgVOdFocyEaSwsrWxqCC8GEhZxLKAjffpLQGrvJvJfJfMam0lOoBimhZmFfKD@45Zv33WjEwV2UILnAU30jNUzgWQcvwaTWZrI9km2Lflqp8dxzoUtyCLgru0HURWkmcI1St8hJlCYHis3aYZ6jwz1SjLngbN9dI/wyFOZNv8yp@XnoSPQPn4nCFw)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 80 bytes

```java
n->{for(int i=0;i<2*n;)System.out.printf("%"+(i++<n?i:n-~n-i)+"c\n",i>n?47:92);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7BCoJAEIbvPcUgBLuZElJEbekT5MVjddhWjSkdRVchxF7dVvMyMP8/zPe9ZCudV/weVCbrGi4SqVsAIOmkSqVKIBxXgLbAGBQzORAXJuoXZtRaalQQAsEZBnL8Li2q6QjPG4Enb0WCR59aJ7lbNNotK9OlzFpaNkPbPlGAR3K@5CC3LXUja40@Bdv98eBx0Q9iZJTNIzOMGTV55MaSRdo8e17vIPlfkVzFdrNbP/wA)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                    // Method with integer parameter and no return-type
  for(int i=0;i<2*n;)   //  Loop `i` in the range [0, 2 * input `n`):
    System.out.printf(  //   Print with format:
      "%"+(i++<n?       //    If `i` is smaller than input `n`:
                        //    (and increase `i` by 1 right after this check with `i++`)
            i           //     Use `i` leading spaces
           :            //    Else:
            n-~n-i)     //     Use `2 * n - i + 1` leading spaces
      +"c\n",i>n?       //    If `i` is larger than input `n`:
              47        //     Append a trailing '/' and newline
             :          //    Else:
              92);}     //     Append a trailing '\' and newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 15 bytes

```
"\\/"¬c@õ!ùX zY
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=IlxcLyKsY0D1IflYIHpZ&input=NQ)

```
õ!ù'\ cUÆ'/ ùU´
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=9SH5J1wgY1XGJy8g%2bVW0&input=NQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 23 bytes

```
V2VQ
+*?N--QH1H\ ?N\/\\
```

[Try it online!](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=V2VQ%0A%2B%2a%3FN--QH1H%5C+%3FN%5C%2F%5C%5C&input=5&debug=0)

Note that the program must not have a terminating newline! If saving it on linux, you can remove the last byte in a file using `head -c -1 <file>`.

I think this is the first time I have used for loops in pyth? Anyways, this is a rather direct port of the example source code in the question (though the 2 loops are combined, and the innermost loop is converted into string multiplication, and the remaining 2 prints are joined into one).

Answer (score 0):

## Batch File, 117 + 9 bytes

Executed using `cmd/v/q/c`.

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do (for /l %%j in (2,1,%%i)do set %%i= !%%i!)&echo !%%i!\
for /l %%i in (%1,-1,1)do echo !%%i!/
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 18 bytes

```
js.e+R?k\/\\b_B*L;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P6tYL1U7yD47Rj8mJineScvH@v9/UwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 80 bytes

```python
lambda n:'\n'.join([' '*i+'\\'for i in(r:=range(n))]+[' '*(n+~i)+'/'for i in r])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcpBCgIxDEDRvacIs0liRRlEkEJPYmdR0WpE01LqQkSvXnUW4/I/fn7Uc9L1NpcWnW/XcNsfAqhFr7i8JFHaIeBcDHqPMRUQ@FqxrgQ9HUmZBzMepOYtbHA1XVAGbv8Y/37RG9FKovleiZntDHL5SezUPeXV8QQkzK3ffAA)

Same approach as the one I suggested to @Artemis Fowl, but takes advantage of the walrus operator.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pepe](//github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 91 bytes

```
rErEeEeEEEeeREeEREErereeereeERrEeeEeeeeeRrEeeeReereRerEEEererEeeEeEEEErEEEEREErereeereeERee
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#_!bsRF$GI-!8g-!c/$.!o$!9a!qF$GI/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 59 bytes

```perl
$_--;say$"x$_."\\"for(0..$_);say$"x$_."/"for(reverse 0..$_)
```

Example execution:

```perl
perl -nE '$_--;say$"x$_."\\"for(0..$_);say$"x$_."/"for(reverse 0..$_)'
```

Waits for an integer to be provided on `STDIN` when executed. Once provided, it will display the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 85 bytes

```
listen to N
X's0
while N-X
say " "*X+"\"
let X be+1

while X
let X be-1
say " "*X+"/"
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 23 bytes

```
+mo`:'\R' ŀ¹mo`:'/R' ↔ŀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Xzs3P8FKPSZIXeFow6GdYI4@kPOobcrRhv///1saAAA)

There is probably a way to halve the size of this program.

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 72 bytes

```forth
: f dup 0 ?do i spaces 92 emit cr loop 1- for i spaces 47 emit cr next ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKaSUFigYKNin5CtkKhQXJCanFitYGimk5maWKCQXKeTk5xcoGOoqADUg5E3M4fJ5qRUlCtb/jQwU0v4DAA)

there's probably a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 46 bytes

```sh
/ \\()for a;<<<${(l:a:)0};\\ {1..$1};/ {$1..1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqKgG/BfXyEmRkMzLb9IIdHaxsZGpVojxyrRStOg1jomRqHaUE9PxbDWWl@hWgXINKz9//@/KQA)

It really ought to be possible to get shorter than this...

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
' \/'{~(,2*|.)@=@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1RVi9NWr6zR0jLRq9DQdbB0y9f5rcvk56SlgkYGK68cAxaOtNHTqIFLKVkZxQMnU5Ix8hTQFQzBDXR3GN0Ljm/4HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 59 bytes

```javascript
n=>eval("for(o='';s=''.padEnd(n--);)o=s+`\\\\\n${o+s}/\n`")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGiNNulpSVpuhY3rfNs7VLLEnM0lNLyizTybdXVrYuBhF5BYoprXopGnq6uprVmvm2xdkIMCOSpVOdrF9fqx-QlKGlCjNiYnJ9XnJ-TqpeTn66RpmGqCRVfsABCAwA)

I had a different idea, it didn't turn out as golfy as the obvious method but I still felt like posting it.

The program constructs the string with a for loop, counting down from `n`, and continuously sets a string `o` to: n spaces, backtick, newline, `o`, n spaces, forward slash, newline.

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 133 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(n int)(o string){for i:=0;i<n;i++{o+=Repeat(` `,i)+"\\\n"}
for i:=n;i>0;i--{o+=Repeat(` `,i-1)+"/\n"}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY5NCsIwEIX3OcUQEBJi_Vkp1noGEZddtGhTBu2kpOmqdOkp3BTBS3gTb2O0FcHNDPPm4713veWme5Tp4ZTmGRQpEmNYlMa6CdeF4_fa6WD5vHy1ylmkvOJM13QALQiQnBQG-odstLGAq2gW4ppCVKoxKtplZZY6kUAyRql4HMfEWzaQntp4Ogj-yWDu2ekHtZmrLbVDmf0n-91VSGi-PvMQcL3wQykvbn0bpwUniGB09CZjQNmrZxJaoPxdkrVs8O66fr8A)

## [Go 1.22+](https://go.dev), 131 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(n int)(o string){for i:=range n{o+=Repeat(` `,i)+"\\\n"}
for i:=range n{o+=Repeat(` `,n-i-1)+"/\n"}
return}
```

[You cannot Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fY5BCsIwEEX3OcUQEBLaKq4UtXcQcdlFQ03KoJ2UNF2VrjyGmyJ4CW_ibYxWcedmhvnzef9frqUd7rUqjqrUUCkkxrCqrfNTbirPb603yfJx_mqNd0hlw5lpqQAjCJC8FBbGh-yMdYCr1CkKPOpslO50rZUXOeQxyohnWUa8Z399lGAyD97Z2-q0bx31nyr7d_KrqZDQfTnzNeBmEUYUBXEbungjOEEKk0OAxIByVE8kjED5uyTr2Yc9DON-Ag)

[Run it on the Go Playground!](https://go.dev/play/p/gtueO56cjAC)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 20 bytes

Uses non-printable characters (backspace `0x08` and form feed `0x0c`) to position the characters in the terminal.

```perl
$_='\.'x$_."./.."x$_
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJF89J1xcXGYneCRfLlwiXGIvXGZcYlwieCRfIiwiYXJncyI6Ii1wIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIxXG4yXG4zXG40XG41XG42XG43XG44XG45In0=)

### Explanation

Stores in `$_` a repetition of the literal string `\<FF>` `$_` (implicit input) times, concatenated with `<BS>/<FF><BS>` repeated `$_` times.

`$_` is then output implicitly by `-p`.