# Length-terminated sequences

Tags: code-golf, subsequence

We all know the age-old debate - should strings be length-prefixed or should they be null-terminated? Well, you've run into a blob of binary data and apparently whoever made it decided that the best solution would be a compromise and length-terminated their strings.

For the purposes of this challenge, a length-terminated sequence is a series of one or multiple integers such that the last item in the sequence is equal to the number of items in the sequence, and no prefix of the sequence is also a valid length-terminated sequence. For example, `[1]`, `[15, 2]`, and `[82, 19, 42, 111, 11, 6]` are all valid length-terminated sequences. `[15]` is *not* a valid length-terminated sequence (it hasn't been terminated), and neither is `[15, 2, 3]` (it should have ended at the `2`).

Your task is to write a program or function that takes a list of integers, and outputs all the valid length-terminated sequences within that list. For example, for the input list `[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`, valid length-terminated sequences would be `[1]`, `[3, 2]`, `[5, 4, 3]` and `[7, 6, 5, 4]`.

- You must output *all* valid length-terminated sequences found in the input, in any order. The order may vary between runs of your program. You must output *no* length-terminated sequences not found within the input, and *no* sequences found within the input that aren't valid length-terminated sequences.
- If some length-terminated sequence occurs multiple times within the input, it should also be output multiple times. The sequence `[9, 8, 3]` occurs twice in the input `[9, 8, 3, 9, 8, 3]` (once starting with the first number, and again starting at the fourth number) and should thus be output twice.
- A number may be part of more than one length-terminated sequence. For example, the input `[9, 9, 2, 4]` contains both the length-terminated sequences `[9, 9, 2, 4]` and `[9, 2]` and they should both be output.
- You may assume all numbers are between 0 and 127 (both inclusive).
- You may assume the input contains no more than 126 numbers.
- You may *not* make any further assumptions about the input, including the assumption that the input contains at least one valid length-terminated sequence.
- You may take input or produce output by any of the [default methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). Input and output formats are flexible (within reason) and the input format need not be the same as the output format. However, the your input and output formats must not depend on the input, and must not vary between runs of your program.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) - make your code as small as possible.

## Examples

```
[input] -> [output], [output], ...
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [7, 6, 5, 4], [5, 4, 3], [3, 2], [1]
[90, 80, 70] -> (no output)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [1]
[100, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 4] -> [0, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2], [0, 0, 2, 4], [0, 2]
[] -> (no output)
[54, 68, 3, 54, 68, 3] -> [54, 68, 3], [54, 68, 3]
[4, 64, 115, 26, 20, 85, 118, 9, 109, 84, 64, 48, 75, 123, 99, 32, 35, 98, 14, 56, 30, 13, 33, 55, 119, 54, 19, 23, 112, 58, 79, 79, 45, 118, 45, 51, 91, 116, 7, 63, 98, 52, 37, 113, 64, 81, 99, 30, 83, 70] -> [85, 118, 9, 109, 84, 64, 48, 75, 123, 99, 32, 35, 98, 14], [118, 9, 109, 84, 64, 48, 75, 123, 99, 32, 35, 98, 14, 56, 30, 13, 33, 55, 119, 54, 19, 23, 112, 58, 79, 79, 45, 118, 45, 51, 91, 116, 7, 63, 98, 52, 37], [109, 84, 64, 48, 75, 123, 99, 32, 35, 98, 14, 56, 30, 13, 33, 55, 119, 54, 19], [84, 64, 48, 75, 123, 99, 32, 35, 98, 14, 56, 30, 13], [14, 56, 30, 13, 33, 55, 119, 54, 19, 23, 112, 58, 79, 79, 45, 118, 45, 51, 91, 116, 7, 63, 98, 52, 37, 113, 64, 81, 99, 30], [45, 118, 45, 51, 91, 116, 7]
```

Comment: Interesting problem, but surely the definition of a string is that it can store arbitrary quantities of data retrievably?  Your third clause breaks that explicitly by misreporting of a substring as a separate string.  If constructing a string from the values "9, 9, 2" gives you the output "9,9,2,9", then by definition this is not storing data retrievably.

Comment: Let's give the OP the benefit of the doubt that they're proposing a fun code-golf challenge and not arguing that the given data structure should be used in real life.

Comment: @Graham If you know where in a blob of arbitrary data your string begins (or, indeed, where it ends), you can absolutely retrieve it. If you don't, it doesn't matter how you represent your strings, you're almost certainly going to find segments of memory that look like strings but aren't the string you're looking for.

Comment: (that is not to say this is a *practical* way to store data)

Comment: @Graham In a system with length-prefixed strings, the bytes `2 3 4 5 6` contain two strings (`3 4` and `4 5 6`), both of which can be referenced with separate pointers to the first or second byte of the list.

Comment: @SaraJ But if you have a pointer to the start of a string, and you have stored some data in that string, and that string has not since been corrupted, then there must be *one and only one* result from reading that string which is *identical* to the string you stored.  I'm sure you didn't mean for this to be a practical way to store data - it's a fun code golf thing. :) My point is that it basically *isn't* a way to store data, because if you don't get out what you put in then you fundamentally haven't stored that data.

Comment: @Sparr That's not the same thing at all though.  Given a pointer to the start of a length-prefixed string, there is *one and only one* interpretation of the string stored at that address, which is *exactly* what you stored.  You don't have to be able to pick up at a random location in the middle, but you *do* have to be able to read back the whole string from the start.  My point is that a pointer to the start of SaraJ's not-strings fundamentally cannot do that.  (It's still a nice idea for a challenge, of course. :)

Comment: @Graham Say you want to store the numbers `2,3,5`. You find a place where you can store numbers, and put the numbers `2,3,5` there, and finish with a `4` as a string terminator. You later want the numbers back, so you go back to where you started writing. You read `2,3,5,4` and notice that the `4` is also the length, so you stop - the data ended and it was `2,3,5`. You unambiguously got exactly the data you stored. Yes there are limits on the data you can store (the n-th value can't be n) which makes it impractical, but for any data that *can* be stored in this format it seems to work fine?

Comment: @SaraJ I don't think it's quite that. - my reading of your rules is that all values must be >= their index in the array.  For any value <= its own index, that value will be incorrectly recognised as a terminator.  You also have a problem with your [9, 9, 2, 4] example - the point of a terminator is that parsing *terminates* there, so it can't also return 9,9,2 unless it's going to scan the entire system memory looking for matches (or at least the next 126 bytes, which may break array bounds).

Comment: @Graham The definition of a length terminated string clearly states that the terminator is *exactly* the length. You might also notice that in the `9,9,2,4` example, the possible strings (`9,9,2,4` and `9,2` if we include the terminators) start in different locations, so if you know where the string starts you *do* get an unambiguous value - the `2` won't terminate `9,9,2` but will terminate `9,2`. The input contains zero or more strings in unknown locations because scanning the entire memory for possible matches is exactly what the challenge is about.

Comment: @SaraJ OK - still not totally convinced, but then code golf isn't exactly supposed to be practical, so fair enough. :) A good challenge anyway!

Comment: @Graham You have the problem with this format exactly backwards. If you attempt to store `9 9 2` at some memory location it will result in the memory pattern `9 9 2 4`, and reading the memory location later will unambiguously give you back `9 9 2`. The problem is that if you try to store `9 9 2 4 9` at some location, that will result in the memory pattern `9 9 2 4 9 6`, but reading it back will give you `9 9 2` (and the last 3 numbers will be leaked memory) because the 4 in the data is mistaken for a terminator.

Comment: @Graham This isn't fundamentally different from the problem with trying to store strings *containing* null bytes with null-terminated conventions. There are some strings you just can't store without using an encoding scheme that avoids using the invalid characters, and storing the encoded strings instead of the logical ones.

Comment: @Graham Scanning through the input string to find all possible valid length-terminated subsequences is part of the code golf problem statement, not a description that the rules for reading this storage format should be to always look for sub-sequences that don't start at the memory location you're trying to read!

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:l and[l[:x]for i,x in enumerate(l)if-~i==x][:1]+f(l[1:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVDLboQwDDx3vyJHUKdSnAckSHxJlAPVgoqUZVcsleilv05ttsrD9tgeJ/P42b7uizmOqS/D7fM6qNIVNSzXVFK35@m@qhm7mhc1Lt@3cR22sSr1PH38zn2/59RRfp@qkqjL9bGNz@2pepVSiwYeDhYGlKFS1AgarRafGLSc9GegNTQDsl6eE1iOd2gCV/5bgdhzIPIwDQxTeg4CIkhHhDPpAlpGjUWMsDzIIwYQT2tgNcjCMqP0RSHmm0uJDDw3RtnuRcrGEyJx0ID/Y4XHM2HLiJVRgc4Z/AwrP8uXi8glIohepxjd5e2xzsumpkri@vgD)

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ẇ=J$Ḅ⁼ɗƇ1
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of integers which yields a list of lists of integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrjZbL5WHO1oeNe45Of1Yu@H///@jDQ0MdBSAyAiG4FyTWAA)**

Or `ẆĖE€Ḅ⁼ʋƇ1` - [Try it](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrrYj01wfNa15uKPlUeOeU93H2g3///8fbWhgoKMAREYwBOeaxAIA).

#### How?

```
Ẇ=J$Ḅ⁼ɗƇ1 - Link: list of integers
Ẇ         - all sublists
        1 - set right argument to 1
       Ƈ  - filter keep those (sublists) for which:
      ɗ   -   last three links as a dyad - i.e. f(sublist, 1):
   $      -     last two links as a monad i.e. g(sublist)
  J       -       range of length = [1,2,3,...,length]
 =        -       (sublist) equals (that)? (vectorises)
    Ḅ     -     from binary
     ⁼    -     (that) equals (1)?
```

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrjaDh7u7bX2ObTrW/v9w@///0eY6CmY6CqY6CiY6CsY6CkY6CoaxAA)?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Nope, they are not valid when they include a valid prefix. (Otherwise [6](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrjaDh7u7bX2ObTrW/v9w@///0YY6CkY6CsY6CiY6CqaxAA))

Answer (score 8):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 65 bytes

Prints the results.

```javascript
a=>a.map((_,i)=>a.every((v,j)=>j<i|v-++j+i||print(a.slice(i,j))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVDLboMwELz3Kzj04CgTZGMMdlNy66HfQKPGQolq1FJEUqQq5NvpONSv3ZndnbXd@tGfmyH0l81o51M1@2rn0y/fC/GOsIrgOB6HXyFGtITtc5jGzXrdrsM09UPoLsKn58/QHEVgAse8resSBQxyaGRQeyS1k7ASpYy@IqkZNHcgJSSJOBcvj3TcJkdhmflvI0Uvh1IGWYGMkobAwkFJB3sP5hYl2UzDOWg2MnAWit0KaAmloakY61wU5slUpTIYFrq48kWUxig4RVCA79FRx1CwJKNjK6vuPXgNHV@2f0hP38OLbz6ET6pdck2W7zm8dv3P5SmpH6/@tn/rDqttchKe5xKnc1vNfw)

#### Commented

```javascript
a => a.map((_, i) => // for each value at position i in a[]:
  a.every((v, j) =>  //   for each value v at position j in a[]:
    j < i |          //     yield true and go on with the next iteration if j < i
    v - ++j + i      //     or v is not equal to j - i + 1 (increment j)
    || print(        //     otherwise, print ...
      a.slice(i, j)  //       ... the sublist of a[] from i to j - 1
    )                //     and break (print() returns undefined)
  )                  //   end of every()
)                    // end of map()
```

Comment: Is it any better to use reduce, and look at `current-memo.length`?

Comment: @Pureferret Do you mean `reduce()` instead of `map()` or instead of `every()`? I fail to see a shorter approach either way, but I've probably not fully understood what you are suggesting.

Comment: the former. I tried to get something wherein I would check the length at every stage, building up the array at the time. I was just playing, and couldn't figure out if it was better.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:l and[l[:x]for x in l if[x]==l[x-1:x]][:1]+f(l[1:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVBJbsMwDDzXr9AxQaeAqMWWBPglgg4uUqEGVCdIfHBf75BOoIXkkBxKc/tff6@L2fc6tunv@zKplpqalktuOW2lXu9qU/Oimppr3so4trx9EWdKTlQ@66llSuW8rz@P9aFGlfOAHh4OFgZUoHLUCBqDFp8YtJz0R6A1NAOyXp4TWI536ANXvq1A7DkQeZgehik9BwERpCPCkXQBA6PGIkZYHuQRA4in9bAaZGGZUfqiEPPNpUQGnhujbPciZeMJkTjowf@xwuOZcGDEyqhAxwx@hpWfla4TpUQEEesQI3Uft/u8rKqeJD7vTw)

This is a subtle improvement on [@xnor's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194242/20080).

The solution we wish we could use is

```python
f=lambda l:l and[l[:x]for x in l if x==l[x-1]][:1]+f(l[1:])
```

However, this will crash on an out-of-bounds index. xnor avoided this problem by using the index at which the value `x` appeared rather than actually indexing into `l`, but this required using the expensive `enumerate` function.

Instead, I used `[x-1:x]` to slice out the length-1 slice including the index we're interested in. Slicing in Python is much more permissive with respect to out of bounds errors. Now, we only need to check that the part of the list sliced out is `[x]`.

Works in Python 2 or 3.

Comment: Nice improvement! I've posted a bounty, which I'll keep up for the 7 days to give this visibility.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
a₁ᶠ{a₀.l~t}ˢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVBBTsMwEPzKqmcLee24ibnwkKiH0AMgVa0ElRCqWrU5VHDjCaiXXrlQIb7AK5KPhBm7VMpm1zO7M2vfPjbT@5fZ4s4Nq@eRTBfzZfMwf7oedT9vN/3@s29bVN3Xe/967L5PqNc4DE3f7rrTxwp5ezXbLNe/h2GopS6NjI0EI4URb8QZ0YmROlojFaK0PGkifGoKCbDgbELzdzkWpBkBveMqTV1K4qwRqvB0sHZ0CgTQEZEtftW5qwBWknSQiSA89wAQQSi3gYKHgoL3tEpKMXsyc1AVU4FSMUfx78ci4HZRCUCLz@GzfKBVSdznZSo978CNfXobmfwB)

```
a₁ᶠ{      }ˢ    For every suffix of the input, if possible,
    a₀.         find the shortest prefix
       l        the length of which is
      . ~t      its last element.
```

An alternate [generator](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/10753#10753) solution using `s`, taking inspiration from Jonathan Allan's Jelly solution:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
s.i₁ᶠ=ˢ~gh~l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVBBagJBEPxK43kI0zM77k4g5CGLB/WggijEQAghgnuQ5JYniBevuURCvpBX7H5kUzVjhO2d7qruqp6ZPIyn8@fleub6l6eBTNerx/FitbkdtD/v993@s2ua9nxA0X59dG@n9vuM/BVFv7lZdM0O5N3vcTubb5d9X0tdGhkaCUYKI96IM6IjI3W0RipEaVlpInxqCgmw4GxC83ctC9KMgN5hlaauKXHmCFV4Olg7OgUC6Ig4LX7VpasAVpJ0kIkgPPcAEEEot4GCh4KC97RKSjF78uSgKqYCpWKO4t@PScDtohKAFp/DZ/lAq5K4z8tUetmBG/v0NjL6Aw)

```
 .              The output is
s               any substring of the input
  i₁ᶠ           such that a list of all elements paired with their 1-indices
     =ˢ         filtered by equality
       ~g       has only one element, of which
         h      the first element
          ~l    is the length of the output.
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `s`?
-4 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVAxbgIxEPzKitqKvPaZO9PwkBMFoQhICKSAhNAJCooo6fKEdGlpQBG/ufvIMWMTpNvz7szuzNqv79PZfL9cv7m@2Q1ktl5tp4vVZjRob1/j7uPcnU7I2st39/nb/l2RH1D0zeZledwe2utP39dSl0aGRoKRwog34ozoxEgdrZEKUVpWmgifmkICLDib0Pw9y4I0I6B3WKWpZ0qcOUIVng7Wjk6BADoiTotf9egqgJUkHWQiCM89AEQQym2g4KGg4D2tklLMnjw5qIqpQKmYo/j3YxJwu6gEoMXn8Fk@0Kok7vMylT524MY@vY1M7g "Brachylog – Try It Online")

Comment: "and no prefix of the sequence is also a valid length-terminated sequence". Seems better to find the shortest prefix (if any) of every suffix than to filter the substrings for not having length-terminated prefixes.

Comment: (Your -4 bytes is in fact what I had before I noticed that it fails the third test case.)

Comment: Oof, missed that.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>69</s> 64 bytes

```
((1#)=<<).scanr(:)[]
l#(a:b)|l==a=[[a]]|m<-l+1=(a:)<$>m#b
_#_=[]
```

Edit: -5 bytes thanks to @Sriotchilism O'Zaic

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVDLboMwELzzFSvRA1adiMU44Aj30nOlHCu5KHKi0kY1KAo95ttLd20UifVjZnZm8beffz5DWAb7sRQF5sJ2ndjOZz/dir1wfRbywu9P4h6s9dY53/f3sduEZ7SEi@7pZcxP2TE/Wtcvo79MYGH01zcorrfL9AtbGAS4DMA1EnYStIRagpJQScBeMmFKCS1VU6Y7RlJFoV6hkvgy4ul7XOskSKumjl0bex/HxPCNCpHyKxqj4kzNAGkM7SUt7aqqCWuYrMjIEKF4Hs1GYIhDHoxMFJkgSRTnRTOTgnnnXkRq1OxmUtVrJDvxWdO/GmSM7PiBOJD0mgMbxlUaqcV1Ep5bxbfqs@XvPAT/NS@b99fD4R8)

Comment: [64 byte version](https://tio.run/##PVDLboMwELzzFSvRA1adiMU44Aj30nOlHCu5KHKi0kY1KAo95ttLd20UifVjZnZm8beffz5DWAb7sRQF5sJ2ndjOZz/dir1wfRbywu9P4h6s9dY53/f3sduEZ7SEi@7pZcxP2TE/Wtcvo79MYGH01zcorrfL9AtbGAS4DMA1EnYStIRagpJQScBeMmFKCS1VU6Y7RlJFoV6hkvgy4ul7XOskSKumjl0bex/HxPCNCpHyKxqj4kzNAGkM7SUt7aqqCWuYrMjIEKF4Hs1GYIhDHoxMFJkgSRTnRTOTgnnnXkRq1OxmUtVrJDvxWdO/GmSM7PiBOJD0mgMbxlUaqcV1Ep5bxbfqs@XvPAT/NS@b99fD4R8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 67 bytes

```
X-Y:-X+Y+1.
[_|X]-Y:-X-Y.
[H|T]+[H|X]+N:-X=[],N=H,!;M is N+1,T+X+M.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P0I30ko3QjtS21CPKzq@JiIWzNeNBPI8akJitYFkRKy2H1DMNjpWx8/WQ0fR2lchs1jBT9tQJ0Q7QttX7///aEMdIx1jHRMd01jdCD0uaxgEAA)

Uses the `-/2` predicate.

There are two parts to the code.

```
[H|T]+[H|X]+N:-X=[],N=H,!;M is N+1,T+X+M.
```

Essentially computes the shortest prefix that end in its length.  However it only does this when called with `X+Y+1`.

Then we have the main predicate `-/2`

```
X-Y:-X+Y+1.
[_|X]-Y:-X-Y.
```

This matches all the prefixes of `X` than end in their length:

```
X-Y:-X+Y+1.
```

and anything that matches the tail of `X`.

```
[_|X]-Y:-X-Y.
```

That turns our predicate over prefixes to a predicate over sublists.

Comment: [This seems to fail on the third test case](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P0I30ko3QjtS21CPKzq@JiIWzNeNBPI8akJitYFkRKy2n5Wur0JmsYKftqFOiHaEtq91hG10rI6frYfe///RhjpGOsY6JjqmsboRelzWMAgA) - it outputs `[1]`, `[1,2]`, `[1,2,3]`, `[1,2,3,4]` and `[1,2,3,4,5]` when it should only output `[1]`

Comment: @SaraJ Ah then I must be misunderstanding the challenge.

Comment: @SaraJ Now that I undestand the issue I have resolved it. The indended problem is much easier to express in Prolog than the one I had interpreted.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 59 bytes

```hs
(>>= \l->take 1[take x l|(i,x)<-zip[1..]l,i==x]).scanr(:)[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU/LboMwEPwVH3oI0oC8GIMdFf6gX@BwsFBoURyEQg6o6reX7pLKj92Z3Z2xv@J6u6a0j@1lP3Vdqy4p757xdlUUjrCp9HOasGXv@fe0BCqKPmFq263PinWI8@N0zkK/3@M0q1bd4/Khlsc0P9WbADWqEBrUsKhgUIJ6qOA1nEajJScmDRftAbSGZkLWK6uElmMr1I47/6NQnFUgsihrlCxpGTh4kPZwR7FyaJgtDbyHYSML70DsVsNokIFhRZnzIsw3txKVsDzoZVcvUQ6W4IlBDf6PER3Lgg0zRqwcHR78DCM/6/ffYUzxc93zYVn@AA)

**60 bytes**

```hs
f l@(h:t)=take 1[take x l|(i,x)<-zip[1..]l,i==x]++f t
f _=[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU/LasMwELz3K/bQQ0ImQWs9LJUa@gP9AmGKCXFjogTT@GBKv73urlP02J3Z3Rnp3N0vp1KWpafytjm/TNtm6i4n4ryGmcrPZsC8fd1/D2Pmw6EtGJpmbne7nqannj6a3C7XbrhRQ9dufKfxa7hN9KyAesq5RoCHg0UFbkE5GUSD2mjOQlop@hUYAyOErkfmlNbjHUKUzv@olGQOzB5VQCWSXkBEApuEuBZdRC1sZZESrBh5pAgWtwBrwBZWFHUuqbDc0spcwctg0u0eohI8I7GAAPmPVR0vgrUwVq0irx7yDKs/a5ffY1@6z/uyP47jHw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 59 bytes

```perl
/(?<!\d).*?\b(\d++)(??{$1^1+$&=~y, ,,||"(*PRUNE)".say$&})^/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU/LasMwELz7K6bGBDt2HK0l2VIf@NRjSyn0ZhIS0kMgOKHpJTTtp1cdJRQJ7c7s7oz28P6xs@G4OiHdjrfIluldmOf9/c2wKeppP6zzYVOWRd73X5kspMwmDz@nClV1Pqf59OX17fmxSGvOZ5PvYjEPoUMLCwONBoLEKziFTiEREpoFy1QpKMJ4rplBgsQatI49/zFhNBCxaFo0FLIEDh6iPNylaBw6so2G99A0sPAOQpcWWkE0NPXinI@yfNkq0sBy0MdrrqIMVuCFoAV30FHHUrAjo6OVk4sHv6HjPr/7w@d2Px7DbLUbw@zJ1kr@AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
ＩＥΦＬθ∧‹§θι⁺²ι⬤✂θ⁻⊕ι§θιι¹⁻λ⊕μ✂θ⁻⊕ι§θι⊕ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU/BasMwDP0VHxXwIIrjJmGnMhgUVijsWHoIiWkNrrcm3tjfe09LC@uxAtnWe09P8nDqp@GjDznvJh8TvfRzom3/Sa8@JDfRm4vHdKJLodU6jijnmdZpE0f3QxetPPBd@JqpkreIQqD34Acn7NZHUJs4TO7sYnIjif6uHbXXioubOGj1X38uJLR60PKel3jOeb@vtVohma1W1QpZatVaAVqtOtwljvaqqoE1QlYGJAiDPxoAHQiGwMLBwIHBG6T9c4LQygzc0siMLitW3ZL1bZ48LMOOBYBXg7lmsbcyqhHcLMu0fN1BNgbWlIdDfvoOvw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    θ                                   Input array
   Ｌ                                    Length
  Φ                                     Filter over implicit range
       §θι                              Value at current index
      ‹                                 Is less than
          ⁺²ι                           Current index plus 2
     ∧                                  And
             ⬤                          For all elements of
              ✂θ                        Slice of input array
                ⁻⊕ι§θι                  From potential sequence start
                      ι¹                To current index
                         λ              Value
                        ⁻               Does not equal
                          ⊕μ            1-indexed index
 Ｅ                                      Map over matching indices
                            ✂θ⁻⊕ι§θι⊕ι  Extract sequence including length
Ｉ                                       Cast to string for implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>28</s></sup> 22 bytes

```
a:-.~((#={:)\{.@#<\)\.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVDLSsRAELzvVxTuYRJIwjyTeeyCIHjy5DkXEYN48QMW/PVYM3mIB0ERkTy6p7qruqZf5qtOTDhHCDSQiPzaDjf3d7fzQ2y7t6o6ni@xHi/d9fE01mM314fD0@PzK6oJA3o4WBhoqBpt3JC0wClXEqomsrqwhMhtE4KElxjkrqWoYUhyRaeJJ5I@ilLSmC7PktnSVtKEgjOuYe3IhZx8HizEruoses@hayyKG0bylu79PFso5aB7aPp3PHgEugvwpWg9BqLaIAQYXsgheCjeqoeRUAaG4zIvZHn@2aqUhiMx5NcuogxOISge@rxUk3UcBQciJo/yqsygDcM11sjmf@CIu/kH8@k349J3ielvN56@oMzv)

Take the empty boxes `a:` away from `-.~` the following result:

For each postfix of the input `\.` do the following:

Filter `#` the boxed prefixes of the current input `<\` using the boolean mask which asks, also for each prefix of the current input, "Is the length equal to the last item?" `(#={:)\`.

From those boxed prefixes that *do* pass the filter, take the first one `{.@`.  If *no* prefixes pass the filter, this will return the empty box `a:` (ie, the zero value of a list of boxes).

Note for J-ers: The function always returns a list of boxes, each of which contains a list of numbers.  This (desirable) consistency is what creates some of the seeming inconsistencies required to correctly specify the expected values of the test cases:

- `(,:1)` -- a list containing 1
- `,:<,:1` -- a boxed list containing the list containing 1 (remember: a single box is an atom)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/),  <s>101</s>  <s>98</s>  <s>97</s>  95 bytes

```c
j;f(*l,z){for(l+=z;z;)if((j=-*--l)&&j>~z--&&j-~l[-1]|!z)for(puts("");printf("%d ",l[++j])*j;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVLbTuMwEH3PV3iDQHYzYeM4V0z5kWweUC/gKKSoFwmllF8vM3bXchTXM3POnDlxvUpX4@v0dr0OessXI8zivN3t@ZgsZz1rYbacD8t0kaajeHgYXn7mNMU9/Rm7VPbff2ZB7M/T8cDjWOjPvZmOWx7fr1kMY5ckQy8Wgxb6cr0z02o8rTfs@XBcm93j@0uEXDadPg6y65dnCQUoXBVUF@2hnKAaWAWsBFYAU8ByYDKgKKK0GbAGV50FSOF0qUHZ5jIASwtm2JNZhnt9WgTUiqhBXlNeol7VWGUfBpyGOFTHJSV6z/ETcnJZUgHZLe4Z/jQ3VoG1msAcJVsEFPnGQouAJPeooFBBIq5orFVq3XzaqVFK7CpJqnWr@D@PghJPo5VUQC06VuXkSxpVU105M428eSDH6nau0RtffMHBzBtxth9qlpmO3H/OeNzhBYjoOlDZPBMvlTpJDLI96X4NMXx1pkfuJcLrZUQIeszXevZkdfltcgD9m2KrElkzH69m4oKdyaa9VVAh6uIcah8rUD4uoPBxCa2PK8h8XAc6jfWww@E2Y@KvyzkaEMiKIobPfnM87SeGZ3O5/gI)

-1 thanks to @ceilingcat

```c
j; 
f(*l,z){ // function taking a pointer and size  
for(l+=z;z;) // move pointer to the end for backward iteration 
if( // cascaded conditions : 
  (j=-*--l) // skip if value is 0 while assigning to j its negation 
  &&j>~z-- // skip if j>z ( before array begins) 
  &&j-~l[-1] // skip if previous value is 1 less than value  
  |!z // if z =0 previous value doesn't care 
) 
for(puts("") // newline to separate lists obtained 
   ;printf("%d ",l[++j]) // print each value from j before l position 
    *j;);} // to l (j=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mR`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
WsV
¯ÒUbÈÉ¶Y
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1S&code=V3NWCq/SVWLIybZZ&input=WzQsIDY0LCAxMTUsIDI2LCAyMCwgODUsIDExOCwgOSwgMTA5LCA4NCwgNjQsIDQ4LCA3NSwgMTIzLCA5OSwgMzIsIDM1LCA5OCwgMTQsIDU2LCAzMCwgMTMsIDMzLCA1NSwgMTE5LCA1NCwgMTksIDIzLCAxMTIsIDU4LCA3OSwgNzksIDQ1LCAxMTgsIDQ1LCA1MSwgOTEsIDExNiwgNywgNjMsIDk4LCA1MiwgMzcsIDExMywgNjQsIDgxLCA5OSwgMzAsIDgzLCA3MF0)

```
-mR         //Map each element in the input to the following program, and join with newlines
            //U is the element being mapped over
            //V is the index
            //And W is the original array
WsV         //Set U to the original array, removing the first V(index) elements
¯           //Take the first n elements, where n is the following:
   Ub       //  The first index in U which satisfies the following condition
     ÈÉ¶Y   //    Where the element at that index minus one equals the index
  Ò         //   Add 1 to that result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>72</s> 70 bytes

-2 bytes by somehow typing `a.length` instead of `a.size` when constructing the range, but still using the correct function later down the line when checking the sequences.

```ruby
->a{(r=0..a.size).map{|i|r.map{|j|a[i,j]}.find{|s|s[-1]==s.size}}-[p]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVDLboQwDLzzFT700EoBxYQs5EB/JEIV1ULLaneFoA@1wLfTcbJdKSb2jD1jMn2@/ux9vafP7fI41TrL2mwefrun7NKOyzqsU0xOa@sHdWq2rB@ux2Wd19mn3NT1HNq3LfVjs@3f78O5o7fuY06IRup999We6eGlSbrrcfelooMiq6hQZBTlirhJvNOKKkSpUXCATWixUmswOoDx3MsCLI5F46EKI/cUsKQIZrjlMM3FxAqABodb41PdugpgpZA5VBwIIzsAcCBYNoGCgQKDN@IUlFy0lFsGmTFlRcrFKP79JLH4M8cCQEsewkR5K1al4CYuU/FtB9nYhGf5Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 40 bytes

```perl6
{~<<m:ov/(<<\d+>>)+?%\s<!{$0-$0.tail}>/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/tasMwDPyfp7jRbEmWrrXij9jDS18kUApboKVdRjMGpXSvnklJGf6QdDrd2V8f56MbTxc8dXgbr78xnl77n3UeY/teNk1Rbh7bIT5cU/WSqtX3bn@8NevbuPhnxpgzsx2K500@j9zZVJJQk2TYXdDl6bZYHfr9Z54tkRXo@nOS1XCwMNCoQNkyyYKCV6iV5MSg5qadCqWgGJA1Z0ZgOdbAeWbeo0CcGRBZVA4VS1ouPAJIBfipaTxqRiuNEKDZyCJ4ELs5aAXS0Kwoc0GE@WYqUQXLg0G2mUU5WEIgLhz4P1p0LAvWjGix8jR58DO0/Gz8Aw)

Regex-based approach working with strings of space-separated numbers.

**35 bytes** when working directly with ASCII strings:

```perl6
{~<<m:ov/(.)+?<!{$0-$0.tail.ord}>/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/tbsIwDPzfp7gJtLYrC3Hz0WTqyovwB8GqgWCd2mkTQuzVO7ugKR/2nc/n5POtP/rxdMZji9fx8lvXp5fue5mpvFjVD5e5fp5r9bXZH1XX767N8jrO/kV1na13xXrIn1aSNE1@76CCRJokw@aMNlM/3Duo7Xs/5E2jJnDo9h9ZukCao@36JK3g4WBhUILSRZJGjaBRacmJScNFNwGtoZmQdcus0HKchQ@svEehOLMgcig9SrZ0DAIiSEeEqWgDKmZLgxhheJBDDCCe5mE0yMCwo/RFMeabpUQlHDdG2fZmysERIjHw4P8Y8XFsWDFjZFSgaQY/w8jPxj8)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                                      }  # Anonymous block
    m:ov/                             /   # Find all overlapping matches
          <<       # Left word boundary
            \d+    # One or more digits
               >>  # Right word boundary
         (       )+?     # One or more numbers, lazy
                    %\s  # Separated by space
                       <!{          }>  # Negative boolean condition check
                          $0-$0.tail    # Count of numbers minus last number
 ~<<  # Stringify matches
```

Answer (score 2):

## Curry, 33 bytes

Tested in both [KiCS2](https://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/kics2/) and [PAKCS](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/).

```
f(_++u++x:_)|x==1+length u=u++[x]
```

Curry's powerful patterns let it beat [the Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194326/56656) once again!

To test it you can use [Smap](https://smap.informatik.uni-kiel.de/smap.cgi?new/curry).  Just select `KiCS2 2.2.0` or `PAKCS 2.2.0` with the `/all-values` option and paste the following complete code:

```
f(_++u++x:_)|x==1+length u=u++[x]
main=f [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 98 bytes

```python
lambda s,e=enumerate:[s[i-n:i]for i,n in e([9]+s)if all(m+~j for j,m in e(s[i-n:i-1]))>0<n<=i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBBboMwELz3FXsExZG8GAcchX6EcqCqUR2BEwE59NKv012bIllisT0zOzva58/6/fBqG5qPbeynz68eFmEb61@TnfvVXtuldWd/dd3wmMEJD86DzVrTnZbcDdCPYzadfu/A9F1Mkd57ztjl@bu8@Vvjuu05O79mQ9ZWAi4CtIBSgBJQCGDd28EbKaCmqmQCY5Cq0KZTRpJaBjp@x7NMdMlDk82lDobHNREwSIVISQsKXHAszQBJDZ2SfvWuKgmrmCzIzxChOCsBhgjkxOSgyAGJVzwzOJk4nE9uRKQuzVYmVvk/jy@aNmCQAfLiJapor3lUxbiKYWrcM3BitS9y@wM)

Takes the input as a list and maps it to a list of lists where each item is a sublist of length `n` ending with item `n` for each item. Then it is filtered so that no list contains other valid length terminators.

-4 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech

Comment: `m!=j+1for` can be golfed to `m+~j for`, saving one byte.

Comment: `all(...)and 0<...` could possibly be `all(...)>0<...`.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 90 bytes

```php
for(;++$i<$c=count($argv);)for($j=$i;$c>$j;$j-$i-$n?:$c=print_r($$i))$$i[]=$n=$argv[$j++];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHRToMwFH3nK25IH0A6pRTGsEOffTLxFYkhBDfI7AgDE2P89npvgfkgo/T23NNzTrv@2Jv9Y3/sHYeNzWW8QA6FA/gUKYcth4RDzEFyiDiIks@tLOSww5GGKyIsQVpycgVD5IS2M7/XZbxS1jnBfdudVbiWa4/WOITALBFGisg9IQBZGc4hfnYLK0YspWaEUhk2JOVCIMOGoHSoIFFBYF@SnVXKZl@aaaMQuCshqWwe8epHRYKnzQQBqEXXJGf5hKxSwuUcZieWDJRYLvdVKsd5Pw9NVR/BWy69uoCtfPi2Z2bVcPjEv6Iahurr7aMZDo1X6Ol0KvlCVJbX1MczuE@6n8Z7cOEWunOrPZeDu/IQc1/18zQS5VW7yqC3p4KAtXtW5/V50qNn7XzlU4t1OWsVqx9Yp1i3Ye2G6cd7pPZDq8c3JLDW9/FTlDnTud1asC4ISmX@Im3g34/Mbei7G3hpLs0Ijf6EmzuLoTNeRotHFgpw3mMRbakMAh8mjXRrPCssa1r@GJOarUlMbKSJjPgF)

Input sequence is sent using command arguments (each number is one argument) and output is string representation of arrays using PHP's [print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

```php
for(;                  // outer loop on $argv input items
  ++$i<                // $i is current index, starts from second item as PHP fills first item with script's name
  $c=count($argv);     // $c is total number of input items
)
  for(                 // inner loop on input items
    $j=$i;             // $j is inner loop's index, always starts from outer loop's index
    $c>$j;             // continue while inner index is less than $c
    $j-$i-$n?:         // THIS IS RUN LAST: if current number ($n) is equal to $j-$i ($j is incremented by one already, so $j-$i gives a position starting from 1 in the $$i)
       $c=print_r($$i) // THIS IS RUN LAST: print the $$i array and set $c to 1 to break the inner loop
  )
    $$i[]=             // THIS IS RUN FIRST: push into an array named by value of $i (if $i=2, variable name is 2)
    $n=$argv[$j++];    // THIS IS RUN FIRST: current number in index of inner loop and increment the index ($j) by one, $n also keeps current number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>149</s> 121 bytes

```
func[b][j: i: 0 until[if(i: i + 1)> n: length? b[j: j + 1 i: 1]if
b/(j + i) = i[print[copy/part at b j + 1 i]i: n]j = n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDLboMwELzzFaOcElVRvBiDjdT2H3q1fAhJaI0iFyFy6NfTMWlPCAt757VrT7fr8nG7@lD0LZb@kS6@C35oEVsoPNIc7z72e1YRL5DDG1KL@y19zl/v6LJwyHiWS4h90Z32GYgHvCL6cYpp9pfv8ec0nqcZ5xndvyHQksJAXQph6eEb1DCooFEyC6sXu@PxuCvIOgWr0KgNIZRr2syWUYp3KNfveao2GlOhtvT/7RuecAURg7JGyREMCwsHUQ52JSuLhmip4Rw0ZzFwFsKBamgF0dCMzz6Xu/BPqUgJQ6PLq3qGcjMCJyxq8DF0zjEMbIjo3MrK2oNj6PwSyy8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/),  <s>35</s> 37 bytes

*+2 bytes to suppress zero-length lists*

```sh
for x;((s=++i-x+1,x*s>0))&&<<<$@[s,i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxPy2/SKHCWkOj2FZbO1O3QttQp0Kr2M5AU1NNzcbGRsUhulgnM/a/JleagiEQGimYKRhDSJCIgYGCAZAHghCWyX8A)

For each element in the input, calculate the index of where the sequence would have to start. If the start index and the element are both `>0`, then print the elements from there to the current index, inclusive.

Comment: RE your edit, I'd say no in this case. Since each of your lists otherwise occupy exactly one line, a blank line would mean explicitly outputting the empty list, which should never be part of the output.

Comment: Thanks Sara, edited.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 2.7-preview1, 50 bytes

Uses Ruby 2.7's new [`Enumerable#filter_map`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187015/11261) method. (Sorry for no TiO link; TiO is still on Ruby 2.5.5.)

```
->a{i=0
a.filter_map{|c|i+=1
c>0&&c<=i&&a[i-c,c]}
```

Comment: Miss a closing brace somewhere?

Comment: Also fails on [1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 121 bytes

```
procedure f(b)
r:=[];i:=j:=0
while j<*b do{if*b<(i+:=1)then j+:=1&i:=0 else b[j+i]=i&put(r,b[j+1+:i])&i:=*b}
return r
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVLBjoIwEL3zFaMHA9pDS6lA1/6Bf2A4LFhjiaKpuGZj/HZ3prjGs5FQOn0zffP6qGsO3f1@9IfGrs/ewiauk8hrs6q@nDatNjy6bN3OQruY1rA@XN1mWi9iN9NGJP3WdtBSOMFiDnZ3slCv2pmrjJscz33sGS3FTLsqoZppfYu87c@@Ax/Zbv3Sef/tujiJAJ@lNpt4lTOYM1AMMgaSQcpAVEPe/lj/C402oyVM4OJdb@MEI9Q9alAkXAN2wvYwhnFyC7sedS8dRGCVoYP6MLdCznkR2J/huy3gVTPnDHgQPrzPZfYJepKKQwj0PUX7U@QuFAF4gBJnjp/iUZUhllMyxVOWmJBkJwIlJgSZigwSGQTmJTkRmMrBEpppoxC4SxFVOYzsvx8FCn9SKQhALroScqBX1ConXA5iCvHQQIoRy/n7ftDN/AM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 64 bytes

```ruby
->a,*s{(r=0;a.find{|x|(x==r+=1)&&s<<a[0,x]};w,*a=a)while a[0];s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVDRasMwDHzPV@hhlLbzhhXHTUzq/UgIw6PJVihlJNua0fbbs5PdFaxYupPuFA/fb79z7@enl6DW43k5eF2H535/3J0v02U5eT88el4tFuN2GxqtpvZan9Q6@LA6fewPHQFs6/E6p@q9@xozok/qm@4nHOjhtc26425uSkUbRVZRocgoyhVxmzVOK6oQpUbBETaxxUqtwegIpnMvC7A4Fo2bKo7cU8CSIpjhlsM0FxMrABocbo1PdesqgJVC5lBxIIzsAMCBYNkECgYKDN6IU1RyyVJuGWTGlBUpl6L495PE4s8cCwAteQiT5K1YlYKbtEzFtx1kYxOf5Q8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 135 bytes

```
A*B:-reverse(A,B).
[]-_. [A|Q]-[A|R]:-Q-R.
+[Q|R]:-length([Q|R],Q),\+((R*Z,X-Z,S*X,+S)).
Q/R:-N-Q,N*Z,X-Z,R*X,+X.
X//Y:-bagof(R,X/R,Y).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVPLbptAFN3zFVZWM/YZYHgZiFrJ@QBLwAZnOqrSiDqWKKCB1Jv8u3sHYvW5aCu1At33PedwJQbTt/1RjOfT5bJb3@XCNJ8bMzZshzvuOkqL9@5K7V4KLciWOheFKF1no4o5aZvuOD2xOUPB8W7DWLm@Ry3uUa1rbCpOKIVX5mIvCuxfW6Vt1a5Te94hFx8ejv1HVqL2Shy4e3lq2qExTO1fKs1zwQZz6ia25zib09Swm5V4u7rhYHvaxtibiR1wGPkSVja8rd6oru@fp@F50hwLwGNvTPM48dslPZu@O3KOrnUvSiJAiAix9rzKdT49DO1pnNiiBCul1BYJYpoIaVJqXHOK5ip56pCVmozKfKQ@tr4Gu@rgtv6V5zopfR8@Ve2zRBbTn7GCb@z3Pbv5I3YcIUkJ/dVbZT9Fdo7CCFLGCBIEpDOmJEUG6WdI52aUYkvVIESWISTFMbIUkmQnCH3IECHR2L3MspGlUSkDxLSY2TdaQMnFEpmkJAFdLLQ4MQFuqRJaqlTOHCQjnM@l/kCOveH/V25Z/57PfuHvbVqef3lxwv/ljtaaflnnCw)

`A*B` is `reverse(A,B)`

`A-B` is true if A is a prefix of B

`+A` is true if A is a valid encoding, i.e. length-terminated list

`A/B` is true if, given list A, B is contained within A and B is a valid encoding

`A//B` is true if, given list A, Y is the list of all valid encodings in A (if there are no valid encodings in A, `A//B` fails)

Calling predicate `///2` with the left argument a list and the right argument a variable unifies the variable with the required result. For example, `[7,6,5,4,3,2,1]S.` will unify S with the `[[7, 6, 5, 4], [5, 4, 3], [3, 2], [1]]`. The TIO link contains a helper predicate that runs all inputs with against this predicate.

#### Verbose

```
prefix([],_).
prefix(_,[]):-1<0.
prefix([A|Q], [A|R]):-
	prefix(Q,R).
suffix(A, B):-
	reverse(B, Q),
	prefix(P, Q),
	reverse(A, P).
encoded([H|T]):-
	length([H|T], H),
	\+((suffix(P,T), encoded(P))).
f(Q, R):-
	prefix(N, Q),
	suffix(R, N),
	reverse(R, T),
	encoded(T).
g(List, All):-
	bagof(Encoding, f(List, Encoding), All).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7LaoNAFF03X3GXM/REah4NlG4MBLIIQcVNmYrkMTMVRIOTPhb5dzujY8jqct730jZVo6fmt@y6SytV@cdEjoIHE48KiJy/TcP3lzsloluSg@xJnTR58nyC1ObMt3IgAq17sZU/sjWSrUEJx90cezjK1h/btKxPzVmemdjesqG8krW@fg0EaOsyn8@M@ZkYGQeNqZhz26HsJ5Q@frb3Yz6UgvaP2xZnDo81mS3RbFeaKyiqqr7peNCNYhvnKGsNUl4fGT5Yg67TTISYYY4FlnnPFtKbTF8sVqBX0BK0AM1BM1BojR88@Ac)

The tricks used from this verbose solution is to first create another predicate for `reverse` because it is repeated many times. Then operators are used in place of predicate names. The predicate for suffix turns out to only be used once, so it can be removed, replacing its call in `f` with its conditions. Doing this removes the need to use `reverse(R, T)` as the suffix predicate already has the same condition.

Answer (score 1):

## [T-SQL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/sql-server/sql-server-2019), 175 bytes

```
with s(r,i)as(select row_number()over(order by(rand())),*from string_split(<Comma delimited integer string>,','))select string_agg(l.i,',')from s,s l where l.r>s.r-s.i and l.r<=s.r and s.r-s.i>=0group by s.i
```

[Try it online!](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cf7c70794e819fa77afbe78dae66c89c)

---

**Verbose version**

```
with s(r,i) as
(
    select row_number() over (order by (rand())) -- Add a row number for sorting
          ,*
    from string_split('7,6,5,4,3,2,1',',')       -- to the split out integer list
)
select string_agg(l.i,',')                       -- then aggregate back together
from s,s l                                       -- joining to itself
where l.r > s.r - s.i                            --   where the previous numbers sit in rows between [current int value] rows before
    and l.r <= s.r                               --     and the current row
    and s.r - s.i >= 0                           --     and there are enough list items for the current integer value
group by s.i                                     -- grouped to each output string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ŒʒDη.Δ¤sgQ}Q
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6KRTk1zObdc7N@XQkuL0wNrA//@jDXUUjHQUjHUUTHQUTGMB) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##LU8xbgIxEOx5Bbp6FHm9Xp83TRoaqoj6RAFSFKVJkA4ipeATiCfwhtAj0aTgS8f4iLzyzszuztpf/Wr98TZ8N/PPzW77PG3wg0nzutuS9SMdroe/w@x2frodL6f@fbFfDHtcfl@GrmuRYUhQRMgSnQeUgDYQCiVlySoOAYG8ngdKVBmWkAvb/jMVggQRQ8yIdDOSAocERxmLqaClGhXuUC4xeIFwU4YGiEJpWOe8@vJmq0iEcdBrpIcpkwlcSDL4E60@RsOWitZVRcYdfIbWTy3v).

**Explanation:**

```python
Œ           # Get all sublists of the (implicit) input-list
 ʒ          # Filter it by:
  D         #  Duplicate the current sublist
   η        #  Pop the copy and push its prefixes
    .Δ      #  Find the first prefix that's truthy for:
            #  (or -1 if none are)
      ¤     #   Push the last value (without popping the list itself)
       s    #   Swap so the list is at the top
        g   #   Pop and push its length
         Q  #   Check if the two values are the same
     }Q     #  After the find_first: Check if both are the same
            # (after which the filtered list is output implicitly)
```

The `¤sgQ` could alternatively be `DgÅ¿` or `Ðθ∍Q` for the same byte-count.

```python
      D     #   Duplicate the list
       g    #   Pop the copy and push its length
        Å¿  #   Check if the list ends with this length as trailing value

      Ð     #   Triplicate the list
       θ    #   Pop one copy and push its last value
        ∍   #   Extend/shorten another copy to this length
         Q  #   Check if the two lists are still the same
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), chars 148, bytes 296

```
r←f w;i;j;v;q
k←≢w⋄r←⍬⋄i←0⋄w←(⍳k),¨w
→4×⍳k<i+←1⋄→2×⍳(j>q←≢v←i↑w)∨0=j←2⊃i⊃w⋄v←v↓⍨q-j⋄→3×⍳r≡⍬⋄→2×⍳∨/{(⍵[1]≡v[1])∧⍵⊆v}¨r
r←r,⊂v⋄→2
→0×⍳r≡⍬⋄r←{⍵[2]}¨¨r
```

because of the problem one has to know index of the element, the input set is elaborate as one set with indices  (`w←(⍳k),¨w`) that in the end were removed (in `r←{⍵[2]}¨¨r`) test:

```
  ⎕fmt f 90 80 70
┌0─┐
│ 0│
└~─┘
  ⎕fmt f 100 0  2  2  2 0 0 2 4
┌5─────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌4───────┐│
││ 0 2│ │ 2 2│ │ 2 2│ │ 0 2│ │ 0 0 2 4││
│└~───┘ └~───┘ └~───┘ └~───┘ └~───────┘2
└∊─────────────────────────────────────┘
  ⎕fmt f 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
┌4──────────────────────────────┐
│┌4───────┐ ┌3─────┐ ┌2───┐ ┌1─┐│
││ 7 6 5 4│ │ 5 4 3│ │ 3 2│ │ 1││
│└~───────┘ └~─────┘ └~───┘ └~─┘2
└∊──────────────────────────────┘
  ⎕fmt f 1 2 3 4 5
┌1───┐
│┌1─┐│
││ 1││
│└~─┘2
└∊───┘
  ⎕fmt f ⍬
┌0─┐
│ 0│
└~─┘
```