# Create an Accurate How-To Article

Tags: code-golf, string, sequence, random

Here is an easy-intermediate challenge for anyone interested!

## What is that?

A thing me and brother do a bit too often is this:

One of us has a problem and asks the other to explain how to do certain stuff. The other just says the following carelessly:

```
How to <verb> in <n> easy steps!
                                   (Newline mandatory)
Step 1 - Do not <verb>.
Step 2 - Do not <verb>.
Step 3 - Do not <verb>.
.
.
.
Step <n> - <verb>.                 (Capitalised)
```

For example, if my brother could not find a pen to write with (Do not ask me why) and asked `How do I find a pen?`, I would probably answer:

```
How to find a pen in 10 easy steps!

Step 1 - Do not find a pen.
Step 2 - Do not find a pen.
Step 3 - Do not find a pen.
Step 4 - Do not find a pen.
Step 5 - Do not find a pen.
Step 6 - Do not find a pen.
Step 7 - Do not find a pen.
Step 8 - Do not find a pen.
Step 9 - Do not find a pen.
Step 10 - Find a pen.
```

<sup>Sarcasm alert!</sup>
Now isn't that ***so*** accurate and helpful!

`<verb>` is the problem one of us wants to achieve.

`<n>` is a random number that we choose (for your information, we mostly use 10 as `<n>`, but that is not important for this challenge).

## So what?

Your challenge is to write a usual program or function using standard I/O and golfing rules that takes in a string formatted with `"How do I <v>?"` as input, and then print or return the (accurate) how-to article specified according to the rules displayed above, where `<verb>` is `<v>` from the input, and `<n>` is any random natural number from the range 1 to 10 (inclusive) generated by your program. When `<n>` is 1, remove the ending s in `...steps!`.

Standard loopholes are not allowed!

---

*Note: There might be some cases where sentences will be illogical, like in the case of `How do I find my pen?`. Outputting `How to find my pen in <n> easy steps` is fine!*

---

Here is another example for further clarity:

Input -

```
How do I make coffee?
```

*Example* output -

```
How to make coffee in 3 easy steps!

Step 1 - Do not make coffee.
Step 2 - Do not make coffee.
Step 3 - Make coffee.
```

### Good luck!

Comment: Can we assume that <verb> will always start with a lowercase letter?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Yes!

Comment: Are we guaranteed the verb will only be a single word? And, separately that it will only contain (lowercase) letters?

Comment: @Shaggy The verb is the end of the string without the question mark. Verbs can be multiple words (It is rather an imperative clause). The second question is answered 2 comments up.

Comment: If `n` is 1, do we have to remove the plural `s` from `steps`?

Comment: @Adám Oh, yes! Forgot about that!

Comment: @SunnyMoon Oh well, that renders all existing answers wrong.

Comment: @Adám I might as well assign that as a bonus task.

Comment: @SunnyMoon Please avoid [bonuses in code golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/43319).

Comment: "any random natural number from the range 1 to 10 (inclusive)" - do all numbers from 1 to 10 need to be randomly chosen with equal probability, or can some numbers be 'randomly' chosen with different probabilities than others?

Comment: @Dominic That can happen, as long as every number has a chance to come up.

Comment: You forgot the part where you send the reader on a wild goose chase across space and time.

Comment: I don't think the randomness adds anything to the challenge. Taking a number as input would have made much more sense.

Comment: @Sisyphus I have not seen much a challenge involving random numbers in CGCC, so I thought I would make one!

Comment: @Sisyphus In real life, though, the only input one sibling would take is the verb, and they'd randomly decide how many steps to use :)

Answer (score 14):

## LaTeX, 269 bytes

```tex
\input tikz.tex\let\s\pgfmathsetmacro\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}\def\u#1{\uppercase{#1}}\def\f
How do I #1?{\s\n{random(0,9)}\s\m{int(\n+1)}How to #1 in \m~easy
step\ifnum\m>1s!\\\\\foreach\i in{1,...,\n}{Step \i~- Do not #1.\\}\else!\\\\\fi
Step \m~- \u#1.}
```

Random numbers aren't very nice to handle in LaTeX.

Example output:

[image]

Comment: I always suspected that LaTeX code is ment for golfing rather than actually working with it. :)

Answer (score 9):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [coreutils seq](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/seq-invocation.html), 128

- Thanks to @NahuelFouilleul for some good golfing suggestions.

```bash
v=${1:9}
v=${v%?}
s=s
echo "How to $v in $[m=(n=$$%10)+1] easy step${s::n}!

`seq -f"Step %g - Do not $v." $n`
Step $m - ${v^}."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3BCoJAFEX38xW34QlFKLlMGNy0qHXLKLSc0oVvjCdGyHz7NLa73APn3GtpQ5gMzXmx92oZU1J6JUaUfbQO@ug@GB1oQsegS2/WbIiSfLfZ5lfYWr6Q0Q40S1GwXylViX0jfepzfJG8kOLgwG6MikyDuFJ/Qn0ksXbzmQ4hLJnG4YRnxw1qDJbLHw)

Comment: I'm just trying to imagine a How to article with 32767 steps. "Do not find a pen, Do not find a pen, Do not find a pen ... And finally, find a pen!"

Comment: OP now requires removing "s" if n=1.

Comment: What does `${$: -1}` do?

Comment: `$$` is a variable containing the PID of bash interpreter.  The `${varname: -1}` expansion gives the last character of the variable.  So here the last digit of the PID is used as the "random" number.

Comment: [9 bytes could be saved](https://tio.run/##JY2xCsIwGIT3PMUZkklSzKhQunTQ2VEqRJvaLn8qCRGRPHtMdLuD@@67GT/nHFvx0Yd9YjVE2SVm77MDP7oXgoOIWAjiQq0QUu@2eoA1/g0f7Oo3jDNvn1ATP5cO@YBC70AuFLDhlVN6@D/@FoLKoniuqck5V8focMK00AiD1VL3BQ)

Comment: however [+ 16 to handle the `s`](https://tio.run/##JY2xDoIwGIT3PsXZFAIxEDtKgiwOOjsaDChFWP5i2mCM6bPXgtsld/d999YM3s@l@Mpi79gS5qhyTD0GDX7Sb1gNMWMkiCuVQkRyt5U1VGs@MFZNTZLQQaZpHK8X02wYZ0a9kPX8EnpET2Q4apC2AZTzhZPJ@m9YF4LCInhvLvfeL85O44x@pA4tJkXVDw)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul - Thanks!  I took your good ideas and golfed them some more.  Now 1 byte less than Perl ;-).

Comment: @Adám `step` vs `steps` now handled correctly.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 99 bytes

Full program. Prompts for string from stdin.

```apl
∊'How to'(¯1↓v←8↓⌽'.'@1⌽⍞)' in'n'easy step','s!'↓⍨1=n←?10
⍬
{∊'Step'⍵'- Do not'v}⍤0⍳n-1
∊'Step'n'-',⌈@2⊢v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO9AEh0qXvklyuU5KtrHFpv@KhtctmjtgkWQPpRz151PXUHQyD9qHeeprpCZp56nnpqYnGlQnFJaoG6jnqxojpIXe8KQ9s8oCZ7QwOuR71ruKpBZgaDlDzq3aquq@CSr5CXX6JeVvuod4nBo97NebqGXHAleeq66jqPejocjB51LSoDuem/AhgUcIGclZKv4KmQlpmXopCoUJCaZ8@lq6vLhaEgNzE7VSE5Py0tNdUeAA)

`∊` **ϵ**nlists (flattens) the list of components of each line. By default, numbers are printed with one spaces between them and adjacent text. Lines are implicitly printed.

The variable parts are:

#### `,'s!'↓⍨1=n←?10`

`?10` random number in range 1–10
`n←` assign to `n`
`1=` is 1 equal to that? (1 if yes, 0 if no)
`'s!'↓⍨` drop that many characters from "s!"
`,` prepend the additional components on the left

#### `¯1↓v←8↓⌽'.'@1⌽⍞`

`⍞` prompt for string
`⌽` reverse
`'.'@1` replace the character **at** index 1 with a period.
`⌽` reverse
`8↓` drop the first 8 characters ("How do I")
`v←` assign to `v`
`¯1↓` drop the last character (".")

#### `⍬`

`⍬` empty numeric list (prints as empty line)

#### `{`…`⍵`…`}⍤0⍳n-1`

`n-1` subtract 1 from `n`
`⍳` indices 1–(n−1)
`{`…`}⍤0` merge into a matrix the results from applying the following lambda on each element:
 `⍵` the argument (current index)

#### `'Step'n'-',⌈@2⊢v`

`⊢v` on `v`…
`⌈@2` uppercase the second character (there's a leading space in `v`)
…`,` prepend the components

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 186 bytes

```c
n;f(m){char*s;scanf("%m[^?]",&s);for(printf("How to%s in %d easy step%s!\n\n",memcpy(++s," Do not",7)+7,m=++n,"s"+!(n=time()%10));n--;printf("Step %d -%s.\n",m-n,(n||(1[s+=7]^=32),s)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7NagMhFEZf5UawaNXSNItZyJBNF@m6y/yAOJoK9TrMlYSQ5NVrJ4VuPzjnfN4cvW8NbRRZXv2Xm57JkncYBeN5e1jvmX4iaWOZxDglrPO@KWeohRMkBD5AcHQBqmHktNjhDpnOIfvxIpQizeC9AJbKdCdVp3OvFGpGTC0E9jXlICRfvkpp0Rj7H/icZQ@z4fTy5zOoBd5uYrkl1Xf7Q796k5rkjN3bjEB2CcWppEHCFaKQFu7t8XIo8AEx4QAOxoDrHx@/3ZGaOf8C)

*+14 bytes due to removing the last `s` in `...steps!` when `n=1`*

*-2 bytes by using `lseek`*

*-2 bytes by changing conditions*

*-1 byte by removing a space `m- --n` → `m-n--`*

*-3 bytes thanks to **Arnauld***

*-1 byte by changing the last condition from `n+1` to `!n`*

*-31 bytes thanks to **ErikF***

*-2 bytes by removing `s` in `%m[^?]s` and by removing space in `"Do not "`*

*-2 bytes thanks to **ceilingcat***

*-1 byte thanks to **ErikF***

Comment: There are two newlines after `...steps!`.

Comment: You can use `"s"+!n` instead of `n?"s":""`.

Comment: You can use `How to%s` and `(b=a)+6`.

Comment: You can save 31 bytes by having `scanf` give you an allocated string (and also stop at the question mark), and then overwriting the first bit, and reordering the initializations a bit; also golf submissions don't have to be complete programs: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/BSgMxFEV/5TUQyWsS0Qp2EYZuXOjapbUQMpMaMC/DvGApbX/dMbNwfTnn3hvsMYR5zoZcVHgJX35as@PgKSoh88dh98nC3DG6WCY1TolqC17LCWqRDIlA9jB4PgPXYZS82tOehOE6URjPinW3MeKlAJUKwmxRP5vcaU1GsNArRV1NeVAoHx8QHVnr/ivem25xW5B8vyizJaPoelXrxbrFQ/e0QcPYuNvcGMg@kfopqUe4QDvj4DYvQ/sCbxAT9eBhHGj3G@K3P/JsT38 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: [186 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY7NagMhFEZf5UawaNXSNItZyJBNF@m6y/yAOJoK9TrMlYSQ5NVrJ4VuPzjnfN4cvW8NbRRZXv2Xm57JkncYBeN5e1jvmX4iaWOZxDglrPO@KWeohRMkBD5AcHQBqmHktNjhDpnOIfvxIpQizeC9AJbKdCdVp3OvFGpGTC0E9jXlICRfvkpp0Rj7H/icZQ@z4fTy5zOoBd5uYrkl1Xf7Q796k5rkjN3bjEB2CcWppEHCFaKQFu7t8XIo8AEx4QAOxoDrHx@/3ZGaOf8C) by using the interesting subscripting feature that C has where `a[1]` == `1[a]`

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, <sup><s>141</s> <s>140</s> <s>137</s></sup> 131 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes by using `$$%10` instead of `rand(10)`, a golf suggested by @NahuelFouilleul in comments on other answers.*

```ruby
$_="How to #{v=$_[9..-2]} in #{n=1+$$%10} easy ste#{:ps[0,n]}!
"+(1..n).map{|i|"
Step #{i} - #{i<n ?'Do not '+v:v.capitalize}."}*''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY5BC4IwGEDv/oqvuVhlDu2WJF461LmjiCybMMpttGWY7q@37PTgwYP3fF0H73Gdo5N6g1UQjn2O63JPabyrHAg5G5mnEcbLNHHAmRnAWB6OmTZlspWVWwQoWqWUyjXtmB4nMaHgYrmeQ@Eg/uMgoSBHBVJZIFGf9bRhWlj2EB/uKHIbQrz/D9wUnKFjdw6NalvOi6/SVihpfKx/)

Comment: I got most of the _plain_ parts, but I'm wondering what did you meant by `$_`, and I tried to replace it by some var `v`, which gave error :P

Comment: @vrintle You'll often see `$_`/`-p` in Ruby/Perl golf because they basically let us read and print strings for free. `$_` is a [predefined global variable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html) (inherited from Perl) that is automatically set to the last line read by `gets` or `readline`. The `-p` command-line flag causes the code to be wrapped in a `while gets; ...; print $_; end` loop. If `...` is empty you have a `cat` program: each line from STDIN is printed to STDOUT. The fun starts when you use `...` to modify `$_` so it prints something different from what was read in.

Comment: And, how does [this works](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v7g0SUNfT19Hzaq0IDmxOFXz//@SokqFzBIF/7yczLzUf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA "Ruby – Try It Online")? Even, we've not specified `$_`. But, when I write just `upcase` in code, it gives error... Strange!

Comment: @vrintle See [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5050/92901). In `-p` mode, `sub` operates on `$_` if there is no explicit receiver. Note that you *have* specified `$_` in your example: it's `try it Online`, read automatically from STDIN into `$_` thanks to `-p`.

Comment: (@vrintle I should mention a subtle gotcha: receiverless `sub` in `-p` mode modifies `$_` *in place* if substitution occurs. In other words, it behaves differently from `$_.sub`, which performs substitutions on a *copy* of `$_` and leaves `$_` itself unchanged.)

Comment: Ah, thanks for details! I thought all the methods on `$_` can be called this way :P

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 180 bytes

```cs
s=>{int y=new Random().Next(10)+1,i=0;for(Write($"How to{s=s[8..^1]} in {y} easy step{(y<2?"":"s")}!\n");i++<y;)Write($"\nStep {i} - {(i<y?$"Do not"+s:(char)(s[1]^32)+s[2..])}.");}
```

-1 byte thanks to Dominic van Essen

+13 bytes due to having to remove the "s" in steps if the random number = 1.

-2 bytes due to Julian

-2 bytes due to Neil

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY6xasMwFAD3fsWryCChRsTuUmIrptChXTq0QwfHAWPLyRv6FPwEqRD6dtcUOt9x3MDbgXF5HgJ6qjnMSOfDZBe2h4QUIFpyN/joafTfUpl39xNksVO6eEC7qyY/y68Zg5Mb8epvEHxiy@2TMaeiy4AEKWZwPUfg4K5JxrpshNgLFirfH0moCrWuY6X@K0f6XEVImGELSWIdm4148UA@CM17OVz6WUlui@70WCrNbWlMp7JZS3mp7ib59zF6eIMJaYQero6alS6/)

Comment: Your program needs to print two newlines after `...<n> easy steps!`.

Comment: @SunnyMoon Fixed

Comment: -1 byte by reversing ```?:``` order: [try it](https://tio.run/##Nc6xTsMwFIXhnae4RB1sObESmCBxKyQGkBBDOzC0IIXEae/Q6yrXUCzLzx6iIuZf59PpuOgYp4fOo6OG/Yi0Xw5mYrOMSB6CIXuGdUu9OwqpX@2PF1UpVZWjKevBjeJtRG/FIntyZ/AOIhvWm6/PP0rc5axfLO39oZhnCZAghgS25QDs7Ymvd7SjTNaoVBNq@a9t5gYRExQQBTZhtcgeHZDzkCm@F92hHaXgbfn@cXsjFeu1PbpvK8q8kjLpi5im@moQl1@9g2cYkHpo4WRpNdfpFw)

Comment: OP now requires removing "s" if n=1.

Comment: you can save a couple of bytes by including the initial space when assigning s: `{s=s[8..^1]}` and adapting the rest.

Comment: @Julian Coincidentally, I was experimenting with that concept earlier before I modified it from substrings and remove to ranges. Your comment just made me revisit it and save 2 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by printing a `\n` before `Step`, which avoids two of the other three uses.

Answer (score 5):

## Scala, <s>195</s> 188 bytes

- Saved 7 bytes thanks to [@corvus_192](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46901/corvus-192)

```scala
q=>{val(r,s"How do I $v?")=(math.random*10).toInt+1->q
1 to r-1 map{i=>s"Step $i - Do not $v."}mkString(s"How to $v in $r easy ste${"ps"take r}!\n\n","\n",s"\nStep $r - ${v.capitalize}.")}
```

Here it is in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RKyIhY0vRKaWs8y4mz9viw), but double newlines don't work there for whatever reason.

[Equivalent version](https://tio.run/##JY4xT8MwFIT3/IqH5cGBxCIjSAmqxEAHpq5dXhMHTJNn134ESpTfHtx2Oel0uu8utjjg6g5fpmV4R0tgftlQF2Hj/ZxNOED/DDsOlj6gbmBDZ6jXU93MKVKhmPJajcifOiB1bryvHnPNbkv8UJXNScfvQ7x21VORnP0zZZVnFbCDUFYwop9t3USxY@NBWijh1QE5BjlpsYzH27CK4s39XEpygnRRBjAYzxDZyFn4KBiPBsJyt6c9iUJcJCa9UUOiynnSLXrLOKQPixb5svqE5oFUr670zsEWeksdIHhDLyLPs2X9Bw) with newlines in TIO (modified for Scala 2.10)

Comment: Nice use of the string pattern match.

Comment: OP now requires removing "s" if n=1.

Comment: You can save 4 bytes with `"s"take(r-1)`

Comment: Even better, use `"ps"take r`

Comment: Also, I think you don't have to count the final newline, as this is an expression that evaluates to a function.

Comment: @corvus_192 Which final newline are you talking about? The after the `->q` part or the second `"\n"` in the `"How to do"` string?

Comment: I thought the bytecount is one too high, so I thought you counted a newline after the last `}`, but it's correct now.

Comment: By the way, there's now a double `p`. You'd have to chnage `step` to `ste` in `s"How to $v in $r easy step${"ps"take r}!\n\n"`. Sorry, I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @corvus_192 Ah, you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 159 bytes

```javascript
s=>(g=i=>i?g(i-1)+`
Step ${i} - ${i-n?'Do not'+s:s[1].toUpperCase()+s.slice(2)}.`:`How to${s=s.slice(8,-1)} in ${n} easy step${n>1?'s':''}!
`)(n=new Date%10+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc0xa8MwEAXg3b/iGlIk4dhUnYpB9pAMzRwylYKFcjZKHJ3JiYQS9Nsde@j0eDz43tneLbubH2MR6IRTZyY2teyNN7VveukLrfI2O0QcYf30CYolitCIHUGgKHKu@Ef/lpGO44i3rWWUKueSB@9QfqpUtlX7TQ@ItH6y@R@@NjOcwIeZCwnQ8h/wfDK3WjeCRSVEestaJYMJ@ICdjfiuP3KtJkeBacByoF52crXYJ4I9XO0FwVHXITYrpaYX)

Comment: OP now requires removing "s" if n=1.

Comment: @Adám Thank you for the notification. Updated.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>194</s> <s>193</s> <s>192</s> <s>190</s> 189 bytes

Thanks to Petr Fiedler, Neil and ceilingcat for the suggestions.

By using the method in [Petr Fiedler's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213626/98712), I don't have to use counted strings and store the first character. I've never used `sscanf` to create a copy of a string before, but it really works well. (Not needed here, but another neat thing about using the `scanf` family to get a string is that you can use the `%n` specifier to get the string length at the same time!)

```c
i,j;f(char*s){sscanf(s,"%m[^?]",&s);for(printf("How to%s in %d easy step%s!\n",memcpy(s+=2,"Do not",6)+6,i=++j,"s"+!(j=time(0)%10));i--;printf("\nStep %d - %s.",j-i,(i||(*(s+=7)^=32),s)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY@xasMwFEX3fMWLQEWynkqaQDoYk6VDO3dsGhCK5MqtJONnGkKSX69qF7rdM5wD1@rW2lICdrUX9sMMFckLkTXJC0LG49th987wjmTt8yD6IaTRC/acTzBmThAS8CM4Q2eg0fWclvvEMLpo@7Mg1ayRPWVIeWS4lWqLoVGqQ0ZMLUXXjCE6sZL8YSVlHbSu//v79DrV5rQGTvcMOx1QhOtVVHP1UR6azVoiycm7lcmBaEIS8zBDaxHmK1BVE3xLuCwAvKiU@sN6cStlPnDM8DJ5nw4oRwc2e@/c7sf6L9NS0adf)

### Original method: 194 bytes

So that I don't have to copy the string to uppercase the first character, I grab the first character of the phrase and then adjust the start of the string to the character after that. I then print up to the character just before the question mark to complete the phrase.

```c
i,j,l,c;f(char*s){for(c=*(s+=9),printf("How to %c%.*s in %d easy step%s!\n\n",c,l=strlen(++s)-1,s,i=++j,"s"+!(j=time(0)%10));i--;printf("Step %d - %s%c%.*s.\n",j-i,i?"Do not ":"",c-32*!i,l,s));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY89T8MwFEX3/ooXS5b8WbUwQRR1YYCZtUv0aqcOiV3lWVSo6l/HOCC2d4d7zrtoB8RSghnNZLD1As/9okjefFoEdkqQ7p6kuSwhZi/Ya7pCTsCRbxVBiMBP4Hr6Asruwqk5xmNkBs3UUV4mF4XWJO3ekAmd1qNhxHQjxi6H2Ymd5PudlG2wtv0XvFfOCrXA6c@yXYmjDSYc2EuCmDKwZ1Yl9vFBNaG@TZVxL7UPcx@iWI9@GdDAugWUquFTwm0D4IXS@je2m3sp65pTgrfa@3BAaXaAyXvnDt/op36gYq8/)

Comment: You can save 1 byte by dropping the last space in `"Do not "`. You don't copy it anyway.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by printing a `\n` before `Step`, which avoids two of the other three uses.

Comment: Suggest `mempcpy(s+=2,"Do not",6)` instead of `memcpy(s+=2,"Do not",6)+6`

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 188 bytes

```powershell
$q=$args.Substring(8,"$args".Length-9)
$r=(Random 10)+1
"How to$q in $r easy step$(('s','')[$r-eq1])!`n"
1..$r|%{"Step $_ - "+("Do not$q.","$($q[1]|% t*g|% tou*t)$($q|% s*g 2).")[$_-eq$r]}
```

Line by line

1. Isolates the task  `make coffee` with the initial space
2. Generates a random number in the range 1..10
3. Prints the title with an extra new line and the conditional s
4. Prints the steps

```powershell
{"Step $_ - "
+("Do not$q.", # if it is not the last line
"$($q[1]|% t*g|% tou*t)$($q|% s*g 2))." # if if is the last line, first char uppercase and the rest of the string
)[$_-eq$r]} # "is it the last line" condition
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU89b8IwFNz9K16fHo0diNV0aoeIpUMrdSojQmCIExDgR2wjVAG/PXXYupx0p9N9nPhifdjaw6HYsLc9NVDBtaeuIuPboGfndYh@51r5NsGHhPrbujZui3clyFfyx7iaj1C@qHEp8JMvEJk62DkgD9aEXwjRnkjKLGSTLFNz8oXtyoV6WjkUpdbkb6MrzpIJaAkF4FjiB4PjSJ3G1Cqpm5eL2whi3g7I5zyqQU0k5C28Ko0pdpliyS/u/V2I5/TjsaVm@IKj2VvYcNNYO0WBQ@9/g7emBgNr5v0U@/4P)

Comment: nice. thanks. you can save some bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY89b8JAEET7@xXr1RL8EZ/iVElh0aRIpFShRAgOvDYIuMV3h1AE/PaLoUwz0jyN9DRHObPzG97vy7U4jtRCDZdIfU3GdV5PTysf3NZ26dszPhDqb7Zd2JTvmSJfj/04T5KUXP1jbCMHqF4yVRTkFH7KGYJQD1sL5ICN/wUf@Eg@UagqrcldRxecDghoASVgkeKHgJVAvcbBl1I/q@bXEYS8u6ec8pDd6VB83sFrpjGb0aLkntz8Fm9KPQ0PHuZG4AsOZsewlrZlnqDCpcV/A8emAQMrkd0EY/wD "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 92 bytes

```
"How to "q9>);:Q" in "Amr):T" easy step"T1>'s*'!NT{"
Step "U)" - "T(U=!"do not "*Q+(eu\'.}fU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcyxCsIwGEXh3ae4/Ze0FQVHK1bEQV2EYrK5hDa1lTRREykiPnuM6znw1Tc5hEAHO8Jb0GNZZquiIvQGtB2eWcEJSro3nFd34ouSuZwlJ/6hyTkWkMgIMxBPxTqhxsJYD8qraapeFzb/tiKEPx7PEWNUfdc77GyjsLe6Rd1JrZW5qs0P)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>89</s> <s>85</s> <s>82</s> 80 bytes

```
≔✂Ｓ⁹±¹¦¹θ≔‽χηHow to θ in Ｉ⊕η easy step∧ηs¦!⸿Ｆ⊕η«⸿Step Ｉ⊕ι - ⭆⁺×Do not ‹ιηθ⎇λκ↥κ.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZAxT8MwEIXn5FdcM10kF9ERMaAKBioVhAhsXazkklhNbcc2oAr1twcnbpOoEoMH333vvbvLa25yxZuuW1srKolZI3LCjdRfLnNGyApTBncMXqnijnDlf/1r0/v4rHjnslAHXN36cu3Lb17lMHlWP@AUJGOlnXog5KzxyK3zibmhA0lHBdZpOmOJ2yNYR3pSrKWHGCQ2mYGLndmZnimVgWs/@I2jM5d5qyE9@ideDPEXHJYBFiXglqxF0a85GF6QJwVSuYBF07Jj/ybMFZ2AGkszZbjwC9fYMvggI7k5YsNgz@BTazI5t4T7NMwzugWv@NR1/Y0LBRsohSyAgyb5EHfL7@YP) Link is to verbose version of code. This feels <s>far too</s> long. Explanation:

```
≔✂Ｓ⁹±¹¦¹θ
```

Extract the verb from the input.

```
≔‽χη
```

Get a random number from 0 to 9, which represents the number of "Do not"s.

```
How to θ in Ｉ⊕η easy step∧ηs¦!⸿
```

Print the header, but only output the `s` if the random number wasn't 0 (1 step).

```
Ｆ⊕η«
```

Repeat for each step.

```
⸿Step Ｉ⊕ι -
```

Start a new line and print the part common to each step. (For the first step this double-spaces the list of steps from the header.)

```
⭆⁺×Do not ‹ιηθ⎇λκ↥κ
```

Except for the last step, prefix `Do not`  to the verb. Uppercase the first letter of the result.

```
.
```

Finish the step with a `.`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>160</s> <s>170</s> <s>168</s> 167 bytes

```python
p=print
a=input()[9:-1]
n=id(a)%99%10+1
s="Step %d - %%s."
p(f"How to {a} in {n} easy ste{'ps'[:n]}!\n")
for i in range(1,n):p(s%i%f"Do not {a}")
p(s%n%a.capitalize())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY2xCsIwFAD3fMUzEEzQFotTC8HFQWfH2iHYVB/oy6OJSC399mrX47jjIT0C7eeZLfdISTiLxO@kTV1WWdEIsthqZ1RZqmK3KUS08pI8g2ohA6ViLgXrTp7CB1KA0U2ABCNN4F0cICY/rjmu64qaaXUlaUQXesBF6h3dvS62ZCrWUaHq5DEAhbRU/uICSbn85hiTe@LXa2PmeTm1Ac7QIbXwGoA9HX4)

Comment: It seems my id()-based RNG only generates odd numbers (on cpython at least), too. I'm guessing that invalidates the solution. Are there any rules that the RNG has to be uniform?

Comment: Because of memory alignment on most OSes, `id(0)%10+1` will always be odd, but you can try something like `id(0)%19/2+1`. It's not uniform, but at least each number has a nonzero probability.

Comment: This answer is invalid as written because ["random" requires each value to have a non-zero probability of occuring](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17564/46076), but @Sisyphus ' tweak would be valid with respect to the definition of "random" since uniformity is not required (per the same meta post).

Comment: However, even with Sisyphus' tweak, this answer is invalid as a [non-reusable function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/46076), because if you give if the same string in the same execution it [always produces the same output](https://tinyurl.com/y5dmdjxx). This is inherent to `id`-based randomization, and the only fix I can think of is turning this answer into a full program instead of a function.

Comment: Turning it into a full program actually saved a couple of bytes. Seems not even `id([])` works for randomness, probably because the GC makes it allocate the same memory each time.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 129 bytes

```perl
chop;/I /;say"How to $' in ",$b=0|1+rand 10," easy step",'s'x($b>1),"!
";say"Step $_ - ",ucfirst"Do not "x($b>$_).$',"."for 1..$b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY27DoIwFEB3v@J606QSS6EDE1EXBxmc/ADCoygJ6W3aGiXx263gfM7JsdpNRYzdg2yZVZCVvpnxQi8IBIzDaAAFaw/5R@1dY3pQuUDQjZ/BB21RcM/fO9YeVSJwu8F/flsIsBrSpX12w@h8wDOBoQD4l1mdSMYFShzIgZKStTGu056ggjutcz9pbU9fsmEk42N6LWSu8pia6Qc)

Comment: The number of steps should be randomly generated by the program.

Comment: @SunnyMoon Changed to a random number of steps.

Comment: [124 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY2xDoIwFAB3v@L58gwSS6EDU6MuDjI4@QGEYFES0tfQGuXnrcB8dzlnxqGMsX2x03kFufbNhFf@QGCgBHoLKEgf1YFopwqBYBo/gQ/GoUh88t2TPqlU4HaDa3qfCVAN2dy9264ffcALg@UAuMpUp5ISgRI7HkFJSTEuvwdDBU9evn4wxp1/7ELP1sfsVspCFTGzwx8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 157 bytes

```python
x=input()[9:-1]
n=id(0)%19/2+1
i=1
print'How to %s in %d easy ste%s!\n'%(x,n,'ps'[:n])
exec"print'Step %d -'%i,('Do not %s.'%x)[i/n*7:].capitalize();i+=1;"*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc2xDoIwEIDhnac4SZq2CmpdjBji4qCzIzIQOOJFvTa2xurLo8QH@P7fvcPF8moYYknsnkHpalPkpk64pE4ttTCbxWpmEipN4h7EQR7sC4IF4YEYRAfY@Df4gMJPziyFihln0nlZFVzrBCO26R@eAroR5FJQpuTeAtvw68yliLqiBU/XRT1vG0ehudEHld7SrDTbdMrDkI7bzsIR7s0VobV9j7hLvw)

`id(0)%19/2+1` is not uniform, but it has a nonzero chance of giving each number, unlike `id(0)%10+1`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 74 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
TLΩÐD≠'s×sI8.$¨©“€ß€„ÿ€† ÿ‡šŠ¥ÿ!
“ˆG®N“Š¥ ÿ - Do€–ÿ.“ˆ}®™s“Š¥ ÿ -ÿ.“ˆ¯.ª»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/xOfcysMTXB51LlAvPjy92NNCT@XQikMrHzXMedS05vB8IPGoYd7h/WB6gQKQ0bDw6MKjCw4tPbxfkQuo6nSb@6F1fkAGSAwor6Cr4JIPVj358H49sILaQ@v0Dq0qRlYDkzq0HihzaPf//x755Qop@QqeCrmJ2akKyflpaamp9gA)

**Explanation:**

```python
TL                   # Push a list in the range [1,10]
  Ω                  # Pop and push a random value from this list
   ÐD                # Triplicate + Duplicate, so 4 copies are on the stack
     ≠               # Check if the top copy is NOT equal to 1 (0 if 1; 1 if [2,10])
      's×           '# Repeat "s" that many times
         s           # Swap so one random integer copy is at the top again
          I          # Push the input
           8.$       # Remove the first 8 characters ("How do I")
              ¨      # Remove the last character ("?")
               ©     # Store this verb in variable `®` (without popping)
“€ß€„ÿ€† ÿ‡šŠ¥ÿ!\n“  # Push dictionary string "how toÿ in ÿ easy stepÿ!\n",
                     # where the `ÿ` are filled with the top three values on the stack
                     # from left to right
                   ˆ # Pop and add this string to the global_array
G                    # Pop another random copy, and loop `N` in the range [1, n):
 ®                   #  Push the verb from variable `®`
  N                  #  Push `N`
   “Š¥ ÿ - Do€–ÿ.“   #  Push dictionary string "step ÿ - Do not ÿ.",
                     #  where the `ÿ` are filled with the top two values again
                  ˆ  #  Pop and add this string to the global_array
}                    # After the loop:
 ®                   # Push the verb again
  .ª                 # Sentence capitalize it
    s                # Swap so another random integer copy is at the top of the stack
     “Š¥ ÿ -ÿ.“      # Push dictionary string "step ÿ - ÿ.",
                     # where the `ÿ` are once again filled automatically
               ˆ     # Pop and push this string to the global_array as well
¯                    # Then push the global_array
 .ª                  # Sentence capitalize each string (without changing existing caps)
   »                 # And join this list by newlines
                     # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `“€ß€„ÿ€† ÿ‡šŠ¥ÿ!\n“` is `"how toÿ in ÿ easy stepÿ!\n"`; `“Š¥ ÿ - Do€–ÿ.“` is `"step ÿ - Do not ÿ."`; and `“Š¥ ÿ -ÿ.“` is `"step ÿ - ÿ."`.

Comment: Another stack based language beats the stack based language. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

## [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org), 147 keystrokes

```
<Enter><Enter>
i<Ctrl-D><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-Shift-End><Ctrl-D><Left><Left><Ctrl-Shift-End>
<Alt-E><Down><Down><Down><Down><Down><Down><Down><Down><Down><Down><Right>r
<Right><Enter><Ctrl-F>i$<Enter><Esc><Ctrl-Shift-End><Del>
<Ctrl-G>3<Enter>
<Alt-E><Alt-C><Alt-N><Ctrl-A>1<Tab>1<Enter>
<Ctrl-H><Space>?I$<Tab><Del><Alt-A><Esc>
<Ctrl-End><Shift-Up><Ctrl-C>
<Ctrl-Home><End><Backsp><Ctrl-V><Space>easy<Space>steps!
<Left><Ctrl-Left><Up><Ctrl-Right><Shift-End><Ctrl-C>
<Ctrl-H>\d+$<Tab>Step<Space>$0<Space>-<Space><Ctrl-V>.<Alt-A>
-(.+\r)<Tab>- Do not$1<Alt-A>
(1<Space>.+p)s<Tab>$1<Alt-A><Esc>
<Right><Del><Space>in<Space><Home><Ctrl-Right><Del>t<Ctrl-Right><Del><Del>
<Ctrl-End><Shift-Home><Ctrl-Shift-Right><Ctrl-Alt-Shift-U>
```

(Newlines inserted only for ease of reading.)

#### Caveats

This solution requires version 7.9 of Notepad++ (at the time of writing, the most recent version), which added keyboard shortcuts to the Column Editor window.

The solution expects:

- the question text to be in the buffer with the cursor at the end and no trailing newline;
- the file to use Windows line endings;
- the Replace dialog to have the following settings: Regular expression search ON, match whole word OFF, match case ON;
- the Column Editor dialog to have the following settings: repeat BLANK, decimal format ON;
- and the Go To dialog to be in Line mode.

I believe all of these restrictions can be worked around, at the cost of extra keystrokes.

#### How??

```
<Enter><Enter>
```

Add a couple of newlines after the question text.

```
i<Ctrl-D><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-Shift-End><Ctrl-D>
```

Insert an `i` on the bottom blank line, and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>uplicate to make it 9 lines, each containing a single `i`.

```
<Left><Left><Ctrl-Shift-End>
```

Select those lines.

```
<Alt-E><Down><Down><Down><Down><Down><Down><Down><Down><Down><Down><Right>r
```

Open the Edit menu, go down to the Convert Case submenu, and select ranDOm CasE.

<sup>(As far as I know, this is the only source of randomness in Notepad++. I have no idea why it's even in there, but it's there, so we're gonna use it.)</sup>

We now have nine lines each containing either `i` or `I` at random.

```
<Right><Enter>
```

Add a blank line at the end.

```
<Ctrl-F>i$<Enter><Esc>
```

Find the first line that contains a lowercase `i`. If there is no lowercase `i`, the cursor stays on the blank line at the end.

```
<Ctrl-Shift-End><Del>
```

Delete everything from there to the end of the file.

We now have the original question, a blank line, 0 to 9 lines of `I`, and another blank line.

```
<Ctrl-G>3<Enter>
```

Go to line 3 (the first `I` line).

```
<Alt-E><Alt-C><Alt-N><Ctrl-A>1<Tab>1<Enter>
```

Open the Column Editor dialog and insert a number at the beginning of each line from the cursor to the end of the file, starting at 1, with an increment of 1. The numbered lines will be every line with an `I` plus the blank line at the end. Thus, we end up inserting the numbers 1 to N, where N is a random number between 1 and 10.

```
<Ctrl-H><Space>?I$<Tab><Del><Alt-A><Esc>
```

Delete the `I` after each number.

```
<Ctrl-End><Shift-Up><Ctrl-C>
```

Copy the last number (N).

```
<Ctrl-Home><End><Backsp><Ctrl-V><Space>easy<Space>steps!
```

Go to the end of the first line, delete the question mark, and insert the number plus the text  `easy steps!`.

```
<Left><Ctrl-Left><Up><Ctrl-Right>
```

Position the cursor at the beginning of the first word after "How do I".

```
<Shift-End><Ctrl-C>
```

Select to the end of the line and copy (the action that I want to know how to do).

```
<Ctrl-H>
```

Replace:

```
\d+$<Tab>Step<Space>$0<Space>-<Space><Ctrl-V>.<Alt-A>
```

... each number `X` with `Step X - [action].`...

```
-(.+\r)<Tab>- Do not$1<Alt-A>
```

... the action on each instruction line except the last with `Do not [action]`...

```
(1<Space>.+p)s<Tab>$1<Alt-A><Esc>
```

... and `1 easy steps` with `1 easy step`.

```
<Right><Del><Space>in<Space>
```

Delete the newline between the action and `N easy steps` and replace it with  `in` .

```
<Home><Ctrl-Right><Del>t<Ctrl-Right><Del><Del>
```

Change `do` to `to` and delete the `I` .

```
<Ctrl-End><Shift-Home><Ctrl-Shift-Right><Ctrl-Alt-Shift-U>
```

Go to the last line, select all but the first word, and convert to sentence case. This uppercases the first character of the action (e.g. `Find a pen` instead of `find a pen`).

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 79 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Çφ`¶J╙╜úº╢ßJ╒♂é↔1S├p$@¢☺<ME⌡┐α∟0/δ-/⌂╙Γâ∙╗-ó≡æñ↕S-α.Wì*°yf╞≈♣⌐Y/)\┬░╛₧níë╛♂9=%▀
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80ed60144ad3bda3a7b6e14ad50b821d3153c37024409b013c4d45f5bfe01c302feb2d2f7fd3e283f9bb2da2f091a412532de02e578d2af87966c6f705a9592f295cc2b0be9e6ea189be0b393d25df&i=How+do+I+make+coffee%3F)

Can probably be shortened by a lot. I'm not too familiar with string manipulation in stax yet.

Since stax does not have a random number function, this program uses the length of the string as **n**.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>163</s> 161 bytes

-2 bytes thanks @Julian

```powershell
$q="$args"-replace'^.+I|\?$'
$r=Random 10
$s='s'*!!$r++
"How to$q in $r easy step$s!
"
1..$r|%{"Step $_ -$(' do not'*($_-ne$r)+$q-replace'^ .',{"$_"|% tou*r})."}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3LbsIwEADv/orNapEhIVb5gIhDDy1Xeq2ILLI8JDebrAMIEb7dRFx6HWlmOrmxxhOHUO5FOSXqKySvx4ilchf8nu3OFZvxd03WkFZb3zbyB6sPQ7Gy0eZZRloUBr/lBoNQD@cWSIF9vEMcuKOYGTQr50jH2QN/JgRUQ0lzC41AK4PN51SXLZMuCur/t@Ds8oFU4zibypdcnwuHz5TS@zW5G4gSrgwePqXhLwmHNb4A)

Comment: Nice one! you can save 2 more bytes: by declaring $r first and doing $r++ without parenthesis:
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3LbsIwEADv/orNapEhIVb5gIhDDy1Xeq2ILLI8JDebrAMIEb7dRFx6HWlmOrmxxhOHUO5FOSXqKySvx4ilchf8nu3OFZvxd03WkFZb3zbyB6sPQ7Gy0eZZRloUBr/lBoNQD@cWSIF9vEMcuKOYGTQr50jH2QN/JgRUQ0lzC41AK4PN51SXLZMuCur/t@Ds8oFU4zibypdcnwuHz5TS@zW5G4gSrgwePqXhLwmHNb4A)

Comment: It's very smart! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 79 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
A=ö)Îç¤i`How {=s8J}  {A±1} ey ¡ep` ·cAÆi`Do not` ·i¢iUÅÎu¹gAg°X)i`Sp {X} -
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=QT32Kc7npGlgSG93IJF7PXM4Sn0giCB7QbExfSBlhnkgoWVwYCC3Y0HGaWBEbyBub3RgILdpomlVxc51uWdBZ7BYKWlgU5JwIHtYfSAtIA&input=IkhvdyBkbyBJIG1ha2UgY29mZmVlPyI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 180 bytes

```
func[s][t: n: 0
parse s["How do I "copy t to"?"]print["How to"t"in"n:
random 10"easy steps!^/"]append t"."repeat i
n - 1[print["Step"i"- Do not"t]]t/1:
t/1 - 32 print["Step"n"-"t]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc4xawMxDIbh3b/iq/br5drNyy0dmrUZjQvmLIMpkY2tEvLrL24baBYN0oN4G8f9g6PzpgWJ5Tx35ggpF5Ms9vQtm@veqYVYHEwNrTO6o/dyQSw4grZSr1BooZV8bVn07zoWSllI7P0zlgNx6Fd05dqfPmfyoVaWCKVnalw5KLIRTFjc/dFpUMo04a2MJiX1XufFmjEGe33BoxOafsCe8J93Dl@MraTEvJL51SAyjyTlkRAwSlbabw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 95 bytes

```
A,P>z9hOT%."\ny6¶†Õ8Âù<û¡*SŠÄ™‘uü'iyÃ",GHVtH%." t²aD–ñö«É ?6^ó",hNG;%." t8Ý§Geµè‡",HrG4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AZUAav9weXRo//9BLFA@ejloT1QlLiJcbnk2wrbChsOVOMOCw7k8w7sEwqEqU8KKw4TCmcKRdcO8J2l5w4MQIixHSFZ0SCUuIiB0wrJhRMKWw7EEw7bCq8OJID82XhcTw7MiLGhORzslLiIgdAYeOMOdwqcER2XCtcOowociLEhyRzT//0hvdyBkbyBJIG1ha2UgY29mZmVlPw)

### Explanation

```
A,                                                                                           # Set...
  P>z9                                                                                       # ...G to the verb...
      hOT                                                                                    # ...and H to the number of steps.
         %."\ny6¶†Õ8Âù<û¡*SŠÄ™‘uü'iyÃ",GH                                                    # Print "How to <G> in <H> easy steps!" with 2 trailing newlines.
                                              %." t²aD–ñö«É ?6^ó",hNG                        # Print "Step <N> - Do not <G>."...
                                           VtH                          ;                    # ...H-1 times.
                                                                         %." t8Ý§Geµè‡",HrG4 # Print "Step <H> - <G>."
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>99</s> 90 bytes

*-9 bytes by using `„` (two-char string) and `…` (three-char string).*

```
ð¡3.$ðý¨U…€ß€„ .ªX«ð«„€† «TLΩ©«ð«„‡š›Ž«®i¨}…!

«®F„Š¥ ™«N>«… - «N>®QiX.ª«ë…€·€– .ª«X«}„.
«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8IZDC431VA5vOLz30IrQRw3LHjWtOTwfSDxqmKegd2hVxKHVQCWrgTyw2AKFQ6tDfM6tPLQSId6w8OjCRw27ju49tPrQusxDK2qBpihycYF4bkD5owsOLVV41LLo0Go/O5CGZQq6CmD2usDMCKANQINWQ@w9tB1sx2QFsCjQZqBJ8/SABv3/75FfrpCSr@CpkJuYnaqQnJ@WlppqDwA)