# Display the exponent from a binary floating point number as a decimal value

Tags: code-golf, math, binary, base-conversion, floating-point

Had my software final exams recently, one of the last questions had me thinking for a while after the exam had finished.

### Background

IEEE754 numbers are according to the below layout
[image: Layout for a 32 bit floating point number]

The exponent is stored as n + 127 so for an exponent of 20 the exponent in binary would be:
`127 + 20 = 147` then
`10010011`

### The Challange

Write a program that when given text representing a binary floating point number to the [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard, returns the exponent given as a decimal value.

### Example

Input: `00111101110011001100110011001101` (0.1)

Isolated exponent bits: `01111011`

Convert to binary: `0 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 0 + 2 + 1 = 123`

Remove offset: `123 - 127 = -4`

Output `-4`

---

Input: `10111111110111101011100001010010` (-1.64)

Isolated exponent bits: `01111111`

Convert to binary: `0 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 127`

Remove offset: `127 - 127 = 0`

Output `0`

### Rules

- Input must be text/string/equivalent indexable datatype, eg. strings **not** integer or numerical
- Output can be any type, as long as it is decimal
- Aim for shortest solutions

---

Adapted from the [2020 Software Design and Development HSC Paper](https://educationstandards.nsw.edu.au/wps/portal/nesa/resource-finder/hsc-exam-papers/2020/software-design-and-development-2020-hsc-exam-pack): 30) d) ii

> Design an algorithm that takes in a string of 32 characters representing
> a floating point number, and displays the exponent as its signed decimal
> value.

Any feedback is appreciated as this is my first question

Comment: Can we take the input as a list of 1s and 0s?

Comment: All challenges here must have an [objective scoring criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria), for which we usually recommend [tag:code-golf] unless you have something else in mind.

Comment: @Bubbler thanks, should that be one of the tags?

Comment: @Adám yes, i will append the rules

Comment: I've added the tag for you. (Yes, all challenges should have a tag indicating the scoring criterion)

Comment: @Bubbler from what I saw, questions just clairified scoreing in the rules, thanks for the info

Comment: Also, if you have another challenge idea, please use the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to gather feedback from other users and fix potential problems. It is recommended to leave a challenge there for at least 3 days before posting it to main.

Comment: Btw, welcome to the site! Nice first challenge. In the future, consider using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges). Had it been there, I might have suggested taking a variable length input representing a binary float with 16/32/64/128/265 bits.

Comment: @Adám I would of submitted it there but was unable to as i have less than 5 reputation

Comment: @Bubbler I would of submitted it there but was unable to as i have less than 5 reputation

Comment: Nice first question! I suggest adding a test case with a sign of `1`, so that one cannot just use the first 9 bits to determine the exponent.

Comment: Yuck, the input has to be a *string* of ASCII digits?  The title says "binary floating point number".  But you actually require deserializing first, if you want to write a function that actually deals with a `float`.  (e.g. like the x86 AVX512 asm instruction [`vgetexpss xmm0, xmm0`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vgetexpss)), or like a simple bit-shift.)

Comment: For subnormal (aka denormal) floats including `0.0`, you still want to just extract and unbias the exponent *field*, and return `-127`, right?  Not the actual `floor(log2(|x|))` of the represented value, AVX512 `vgetexpps` does: (`-Inf` for an input of 0, and values below -127 for non-zero subnormals, matching [the pseudocode in the documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vgetexpps#tbl-5-15))

Comment: @PeterCordes honestly, just finishing high school software, and this being my first question, im not 100% sure, given the rules i wrote, -127 would be correct, feel free to edit or suggest an edit as you clearly understand it better than me

Comment: If we could take input as a floating point number, I think `frexpf` would be a valid C answer.

Comment: It's pretty clear the existing answers are just extracting that bit-field and subtracting 127; any change would invalidate them so don't do that.  Either one is a valid thing to do.  If you were going to use the exponent as part of a `log` implementation you'd often want the mathematical version (and normalize the mantissa for subnormals by left shifting it).  This sets you up for using a polynomial approximation of `log` over a 0.5 .. 1.0 range for the mantissa, plus the exponent value.  The actual exponent field value is just an encoding detail of `binary32`.

Comment: Holy heck I did this exam too! I knew something seemed familiar!

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda s:int(s[1:9],2)-127
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU5BCoMwELz7ir1tAhESFaRC@hH1YG2Cpa1Kkh6K@PY0Se2pAzvMsrO7s77dtMyl17Lzj@F5uQ5gm9vsiG1Fc@pZQXNR1N4p6yxIIBkEEORcBESK6q8Esryi7DAnn/gtBPru8SgiIQMezDQbJzXelYl/sHsVdTWGUVKiRJrpxYBjCm4zpDxNuh/tmjiamtXE7Bo3t0N@hs3ssB1XWyOl6nek/gM)

Comment: How dare you beat me by 5 seconds with the exact same code!

Comment: @pxeger I wrote a full test suite so as not to rush you! :D

Answer (score 8):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>55</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>40</s></sup> 36 bytes

Saved <s>2</s> 6 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!
Saved <s>2</s> a whopping 13 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!

```c
#define f(s)strtol(s+1,s[9]=0,2)-127
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHbboMwDH3vV1hMSKENGpdNU8XYy7SvaHlIQ9KidRThSGOr@PUxh0vbdS@NZMucHI7tE@lvpey6u1zpolSgGXpoanPYM1yEHFfLLA145Plh9NQVpYEPUZTMmx1nQEfuRD0Ho9DgKoMUjk4QhHRsstW/CB0OTngDp6fcpDPxKA30wBY2OW3ST2nHVk2lpFH5MKb/wMFGGFEKRlq/jNwp@a5qovXrrJu3aN0sXykebcuL73iS14camO1RlLlq6LcgGctnwOJbHTSbunv3IzA/IQksFj3bg8HTs69IWoO3PSFL/tzDZhXHFxi9mqy@2IajdwbtWIJkNNtcoYrQkynX@lVNFM0cF8F/ATcHF9cl7Y8cBIfJI5WmIhtl21nb/Ui9F1vs/M9f)

Comment: [The built-in approach](https://tio.run/##hVDbToQwEH3fr5iQYNrdNgK7xhiEF@NXCA9NaXeJK2wYEomEXxfbclHXByeZZnrmzDmZkfwo5ThqIk@i2SLtMSHYNm19JsgCFtE0jfY3YXRPuXniYSyrFt5EWRG66Tdgwg1Cq7DFlxwS6L0gCE3Yx1Z/MvQYeOF/nCF26tZOdRclW1VM8vzAgB/mtjOXJyVfVWPazj7rnqOse3gyeWetfvz3i6yuGyBWu6wK1ZmxIJ7LR8DyQ9WaLK70dga2KxLDbufYFKYbfN8BjdZ0C0fI47Vv3YTpaoL0N6oMuu54PXZpDEUTz0fgKfgF@JhVZi1kIBgsq6skEfksO2yG8VPqszjiyN@/AA).

Comment: @Arnauld Had to tweek it a bit to get it working for other testcases and saved another byte! Great idea - thanks! :D

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```hs
foldl1(\x y->x*2+y-1).take 8.tail
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPy0/JyXHUCOmQqFS165Cy0i7UtdQU68kMTtVwQJIZeb8z03MzFOwVSgoyswrUVBRSFOINtAx0DGEQgM4bUAkbRj7/19yWk5ievF/3eSCAgA)

Input is a list of integers 0 or 1.

It's slightly shorter to `foldl1` by `x*2+y-1` than to subtract 127 at the end. This works because

```hs
  foldl1 (\x y->x*2+y-1) [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
= ((((((a*2+b-1)*2+c-1)*2+d-1)*2+e-1)*2+f-1)*2+g-1)*2+h-1
= a*128 + b*64-64 + c*32-32 + d*16-16 + e*8-8 + f*4-4 + g*2-2 + h-1
= 128a + 64b + 32c + 16d + 8e + 4f + 2g + h - 127
= fromBinary[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]-127
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <sup><s>8</s></sup> 7 bytes

```
¦8£CƵQ-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0DKLQ4udj20N1P3/38DAEAhABIiFgQ0B)

```
¦8£CƵQ-
¦             remove first element
 8£           take next 8 elements
   C          convert from binary string to an integer
    ƵQ        push 127
      -       subtract
```

Thanks to Kevin for -1 byte

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. Was about to post my answer, lol. The `žy<` can be `ƵQ`. [See the *How to compress large integers?* section in this tip of mine.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210)

Comment: This is still 7 bytes, not 6

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing lol too tired for this...

Answer (score 6):

## x86 machine code, 14 bytes

Same machine code works in 32 or 64-bit mode.  (Same length for 16-bit mode would be easy with different regs).  Callable from C as x86-64 System V `int8_t getexp(const char *b2_str);`

```
    23        ; input: char *str in RDI
    24        ; return: int8_t AL; (calling convention allows garbage in high bytes of RAX)
    25                         getexp_scalar:
    26 00000030 6A09              push 9                 ; sign bit gets shifted out the top.
    27 00000032 59                pop  rcx
    28 00000033 B030              mov  al, '0'
    29                         .loop:
    30 00000035 AE                 scasb                    ; set FLAGS like cmp '0', [rdi]  would, if it was encodeable
    31 00000036 10D2               adc  dl,dl               ; DL = DL<<1 | CF, rotate CF into DL.
    32 00000038 E2FB              loop .loop
    33 0000003A 8D4281            lea  eax, [rdx-127]      ; no shorter than sub dl, 127  or  xchg eax,edx / sub al,127
    34 0000003D C3                ret
```

We just do base 2 ASCII->integer conversion for 9 bits, letting the first bit (sign bit) overflow off the top of DL.  The 8-bit return value is only the 8-bit AL register, as a 2's complement binary integer.

`adc  dl,dl` to rotate CF into DL is more efficient on modern CPUs than `rcl dl, 1` (rotate through carry, i.e. shift in CF). They're equivalent except for some FLAGS output semantics.  I could have used EDX for the same code size; that would simply leave different garbage in the high bytes outside the AL return value in RAX.   (And yes, high garbage above narrow return values is [100% allowed by standard x86 calling conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706721/is-a-sign-or-zero-extension-required-when-adding-a-32bit-offset-to-a-pointer-for/36760539#36760539).)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVVtb9s2EP7OX/GgX/pme5a7tZ3dYUhXdAhgYECyDwOKwDiJtEREIhWScuRh/z07Uo4VOxsqwHrhkc89d/fcmbxXTV7vp4Z88/BAtS4NsvdihUC3yi9RWOMDiooc3vjgoA2uvlyy3anQOcM7tAkfNwEX6xWASpcV8n1QHnaLq4u/0NAeuUJJLqdSgTxa5eADGUlOoqC61qaMfnbKBM3uZqJUQfXtxrOR3FLgcLWdr/Azzq8VfGSd6wDN6M4WiqOSYA9gJA9f6W3gBdsFhEoh2HY2gtoWcEV/XGjsDqB6gpfzl2JWW9uODJiRz/EfF3NQAV/XF79fo9a3CkXTRoAJvjmpb4B729VyAr0F07znLChTWKkor9URnWQByHoi62foX9b4hW@fPmX4B799ncDZQEHxa8y/ZdMYUaSMRHxcUgQo6hOdfpotPtw8IhvL@bEucFFCRQa@yyMH8B7AOqAvqjKdVbLHD8nO2WHzEZ2lIMQT6WjTdmGJq@vLScx5@rhYn1Z1cV7W5wU5yz3HJX0@fsbypjplT7akOOUhzjcLvIWj/ua7qTnLzf9EdgigafonrDiFiRi7is87fub@ntp4mnq@syY9NYodmTJUsQFYYdwRbnDp9dvs6HCwDEcH6bAx@Yg9NXVqp5xXeJXrcqqM1GRes1eSsdmispmeNdxG2GpVyxkLlnbcitln7PwsKfvA7tGhrw5aSw4/nAR1n1qKxZWamhtfUTE0dwLmkLz@e@hoX9cSTTNniNmTWO6Gl7jO@I@Gli2Nv82HpLP16LOl4hY7VQTW3TBJNLdvEniWHB9pd4cupEGpYqzXg1Rb6urA77Uoa5tTjQ2PGxfE8FiKOKh2TELeEfaJ3TcebfNNdmyKqK2TjDOD9fXn6VY7H34VYhQOl2g8Lo7zA1zXSTSmpTjkgFE@4uCGt/oeKm8nHMiIms6eYCaA0/45x@jPMOT3McQj3wgQ9zPAMYBUnMW71Fx@74cQno891euwKZ3t2lcx@zvO9mshViv8efkHz2KuncfHaRRS3Bnnfuh81Exn4tRWPBO9xd52qFiqMc/SJikvflpgyvf3PPimP0b58SaWhSI5E8KzSPi/AjNnJQU69Oi7hRgiXkLmeDGfZ3zFW3x79stePPwL) 3 versions with a test caller.
(Including alternate 15-byte scalar version using `lodsb` / `and al, 1` / `lea edx, [rdx*2 + rax]`)

## x86-64 SIMD (MMXext+MOVBE) machine code, 20 bytes

Having base-2 digits in MSB-first printing order is a major inconvenience for little-endian x86, where the lowest SIMD vector element comes from the lowest address in memory.  x86 lacks a bit-reverse like ARM's `rbit`, so I used x86-64 features to byte-reverse 8 bytes.  Without that, `movq mm0, [e/rdi+1]` (4B) / `pslld mm0,7` (4B) would be 32-bit-mode compatible and work on a Pentium III (`pmovmskb r32, mm` was new with SSE, [aka MMXext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_MMX), so not original P5 Pentium-MMX).

```
                             ; input: char *RDI;   result int8_t AL
                             ; clobbers: MM0.  Leaves FPU in MMX state (no EMMS)
    12                         getexp_mmx:
    14 00000010 480F38F04701          movbe    rax, [rdi+1]   ; byte-reverse (big-endian) load of the exponent field.  saves 1B vs. mov + bswap
    15 00000016 48C1E007              shl      rax, 7         ; low bit to high in each byte.  same size as pslld mm0, 7.
    16 0000001A 480F6EC0              movq     mm0, rax
    17 0000001E 0FD7C0                pmovmskb eax, mm0       ; pack vector high bits into 1 byte
    18 00000021 2C7F                  sub      al, 127
    19 00000023 C3                    ret
; size = 0x24 - 0x10 = 0x14 = 20 B
```

MMX instructions typically need 1 fewer prefix byte than SSE2 and later; if you were doing this for real you'd probably use XMM0, and avoid the EMMS (exit MMX state) that real code would normally use.  (And maybe a `pshufb` for the byte reverse if you have SSSE3, to avoid bouncing through integer regs...)  This should still be much faster than a loop with adc and false dependencies, and the slow `loop` instruction itself.  **It's handy that the exponent field is exactly 8 bits wide.**  Doing this for `double` would need an SSE2 16-byte load (or 2 byte reverses and annoying shuffles to combine into a 16-byte vector), and would have to mask away the sign bit.

lodsb (1) + lodsq (2) + bswap rax (3) is the same total length as `movbe rax, [rsi+1]` (6), although that would make this portable to machines without `movbe` (Atom, Haswell and later).

---

For subnormal (aka denormal) floats including `0.0`, this just returns `-127`, the  unbiased the exponent *field*, as requested by the question.  And `-128` (overflowed from +128) for Inf / NaN inputs.  (I only realized this overflow issue after the fact, posting anyway because all 255 possible outputs are *unique*, and that puts both special exponents at adjacent values so the caller can test for subnormal or inf/nan with `e <= -127`.)

It doesn't return the actual `floor(log2(|x|))` of the represented value like AVX512 `vgetexpps xmm, xmm` does: (`-Inf` for an input of 0, and values below -127 for non-zero subnormals, matching [the pseudocode in the documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vgetexpps#tbl-5-15)).

So even if we could take input as an actual *binary* floating-pointer number in [IEEE754 binary32 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) (aka `float`) in an XMM register, we couldn't just use that one 6-byte AVX512 instruction to produce an integer-valued `float` result.

---

#### not competing AVX2 version, 15 bytes

This takes its arg as 32 bytes of ASCII digits in a YMM register, but they have to be in least-significant-digit first order, hence not competing.

```
     2                         getexp_avx2_ymm_reversed:
     3             ; input: LSD-first ASCII digits in ymm0.  Probably can't justify that and would need to byte-reverse 
     5 00000000 C5FD72F007             vpslld     ymm0, ymm0, 7
     6 00000005 C5FDD7C0               vpmovmskb  eax, ymm0
     7 00000009 C1E817                 shr        eax, 23         ; AL = exponent
     8 0000000C 2C7F                   sub        al, 127
     9 0000000E C3                     ret
```

Fun fact: AVX-512 allows `vpslld ymm0, [rdi], 7`, if you had bytes in the LSD-first order in memory.  (7 bytes including 4-byte EVEX, so an extra 2 bytes to take a char* instead of YMM arg.)

Answer (score 5):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╞8<å♣(-
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1HkWNoeXPpq5WEP3/38lAwNDIAARIBYGNlTigioB8g1AGBOAlBiCJSEGYQFKAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
╞        # Remove the first character of the (implicit) input-string
 8<      # Slice to only keep the first 8 characters of the string
   å     # Convert it from a binary-string to a base-10 integer
    ♣    # Push constant 128
     (   # Decrease it by 1 to 127
      -  # Subtract it from the integer
         # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 23 bytes

```js
f=
b=>(`0b${b}0`>>>24)-127
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Uses the fact that `>>>` truncates to 32 bits.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, <sup><s>24</s> <s>23</s></sup> 20 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus)*
*-3 bytes using `-n` command-line flag, inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213642/83605)*

```ruby
p$_[1,8].to_i(2)-127
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AlPtpQxyJWryQ/PlPDSFPX0Mj8/38DA0MgABEgFgY25ALLGcIUAQmIWgMQA0T8yy8oyczPK/6vmwcA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org),  <s>26</s>   <s>31</s>  29 bytes

Converted to a valid anonymous function, thanks to [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
-2 bytes thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)

```
{it.slice(1..8).toInt(2)-127}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp5FYlF5speBYVJRYaRNcUpSZl26nqVDNpQAFZYk5CmkVVgoaEDlNBV07Bc@8EgXb/9WZJXrFOZnJqRqGenoWmnol@UBxDSNNXUMj89r/nAVA5SU5eRppFRpKBgaGQAAiQCwMbKikqclV@x8A)

Comment: `s` is not defined here. You can do `s=>s.slice` or `{it.slice` instead

Comment: @user - `s` is defined, and it's working! Any errors on your side?

Comment: No, I meant that s is not declared inside your snippet, it’s the parameter to a function outside, and I’m not sure that’s allowed.

Comment: You need to include the part that defines `s` to be a function parameter in the byte count. Otherwise it is invalid.

Comment: @user - Can you provide an example?

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp5FYlF5speBYVJRYaRNcUpSZl26nqVDNpQAFZYk5CmkVVgoaEDlNBV07Bc@8EgXb/9XFunbFesU5mcmpGoZ6ehaaeiX5QBkNI01dQyPz2v@cBUANJTl5GmkVGkoGBoZAACJALAxsqKSpyVX7HwA) is a valid lambda function.

Comment: As user mentioned, [this also works](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp5FYlF5speBYVJRYaRNcUpSZl26nqVDNpQAFZYk5CmkVVgoaEDlNBV07Bc@8EgXb/9WZJXrFOZnJqRqGenoWmnol@UBxDSNNXUMj89r/nAVA5SU5eRppFRpKBgaGQAAiQCwMbKikqclV@x8A), where `it` is an [implicit single parameter of a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773351/what-is-the-it-in-kotlin-lambda-body).

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](http://desmos.com/calculator), <s>42+9=51</s> <s>40+9=49</s> 30 bytes

```
f(l)=\sum_{i=0}^7l[9-i]2^i-127
```

Input as a list of 1's and 0's.

[image]

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/urde7webzo)

Comment: Always love Desmos creations! Nice

Comment: @MaximilianRose Thanks! I spend quite a lot of time using Desmos so I thought I would just try my skills at code golf using Desmos.

Comment: I use to spend a lot of time on desmos, that's cool. Never even thought about shortcuts like "total" before.

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 22 bytes

```bash
echo $[2#${1:1:8}-127]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BJdpIWaXa0MrQyqJW19DIPPb///8GBoZAACJALAxsCAA)

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>37</s> 27 bytes

Input is from STDIN, output is to STDOUT.

```bash
expr $[2#`cut -b2-9`] - 127
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7WioEhBJdpIOSG5tERBN8lI1zIhVkFXwdDI/P9/AwNDIAARIBYGNgQA)

### Explanation

```bash
expr                             # Evaluate the following:

         `cut -b2-9`             #     Slice all characters from the 2nd character
                                 #     to the 9th character in standard input

     $[2#           ]            #     Convert it from base 2
                      - 127      #     And subtract by 127
```

Comment: welcome, new contributor! ~~oh wait~~

Comment: [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqFZ/T81OSNfQSXaSFml2tDK0MqiVtfQyDz2fy1XmoKBgSEQgAgQCwMbApWAZQ1hyoAERLUBiAEi/gMA).

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

ty to @Bubbler and @Kevin Cruijssen for corrections

```python
lambda n: sum([2**i*int(n[8-i])for i in range(8)])-127
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSHPSqG4NFcj2khLK1MrM69EIy/aQjczVjMtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VcNCM1ZT19DI/P9/MwtTyxQA)

Comment: Answers must be a function (taking input from function parameter) or a full program (taking input from stdin), i.e. you can't assume that the input is already stored in a variable. [You can convert it to an anonymous lambda instead.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqrg0VyPaSEsrUyszr0QjL9pCNzNWUyEtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VcNAx0IzVlPX0Mj8f0ERSF2ahrqBgSEQgAgQCwMbqmtq/gcA)

Comment: I generally recommend waiting a week before answering your own challenge, especially if you do so in a popular language like Python. This is to give others a chance to discover and think about the task. You obviously know the game is on, and you've already spent time thinking about it.

Comment: You can remove the space at `)for` and the `0,` in the `range(8)` (after converting it to a valid lambda as mentioned by _@Bubbler_).

Comment: @Adám That's a big *meh*. You can just ignore the answer. Having an answer doesn't stop anyone from thinking about the task. To me, that type of policing goes far beyond the spirit of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Cody Gray and anyway I was so caught up with converting the solution I used in the actual exam which was psudocode without base conversion functions that I completely forgot about ```int(n, 2)``` to change base, which let another person find a shorter solution, I won't remove this one because I'm still proud of finding a nice use of list comprehension but I didn't expect it to be upvoted to the top of anything

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

```apl
¯127+2⊥8↑1↓⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////9B6QyNzbaNHXUstHrVNNHzUNvlR16L/aY/aJjzq7XvU1fyod82j3i2H1hsDZR/1TQ0OcgaSIR6ewf/TFAyA0BAKDeC0AZG0IQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 63 bytes

```
2=M&!`.{8}
1
01
+`10
011
$
-127$*
(1*)-\1
-
^0*(-)?(1*)-?
$1$.2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fyNZXTTFBr9qilsuQy8CQSzvB0ABIG3KpcOkaGpmraHFpGGpp6sYYculyxRloaehq2oMF7LlUDFX0jP7/NwAqNjQEESAWBjYEAA) Explanation:

```
2=M&!`.{8}
```

Get the second overlapping 8-character substring.

```
1
01
+`10
011
```

Convert to binary (may leave leading `0`s).

```
$
-127$*
(1*)-\1
-
```

Subtract 127 (may leave trailing `-`).

```
^0*(-)?(1*)-?
$1$.2
```

Convert to decimal, removing garbage.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
127-~1{8#.\]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DY3MdesMqy2U9WJi/2tyKXClJmfkK6QBVRgoGEKhAZw2IJI2/A8A)

```
        #.        convert to binary
       8  \       all the infixes with length 8
           ]      of the argument
     1{           take the second one (0-indexed) 
127-~             subtract 127
```

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 27 bytes

Uses Lynn's [clever approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214774/95792)

```scala
_.slice(1,9)reduce(_*2+_-1)
```

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pUShRsE7TVSCWYzYpJK8yg)

## Scala, 29 bytes

```scala
n=>BigInt(n.slice(1,9),2)-127
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/9DgvUdWjRki0fkZ2BXCjhQ)

Very straightforward. Takes a `String`, parses the exponent's bits as an integer in binary, then subtracts 127, returning a `BigInt`.

## Scala, 29 bytes

```scala
n=>(BigInt(n.tail,2)>>23)-127
```

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pSvsZAQ3S5aOOVkOhC2kjg)

Unfortunately, because of operator precedence, the outer parentheses are needed.

## Scala, 29 bytes

```scala
_.slice(1,9)./:(0)(_*2+_)-127
```

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bAxtSdGJRKqCgeNT3py96Q)

Yet another solution, this time taking a list of digits (`List[Int]`).

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <strike>120</strike> <strike>115</strike> <strike>42</strike> 32 bytes

```
s=>Convert.ToByte(s[1..9],2)-127
```

<sup>Thanks to @SunnyMoon for realising that the code is not actually 120 bytes (-2)
Thanks to @Sunnymoon for slaying 3 *sneaky* spaces in the code (-3)
Thanks to @user for coding a much **much** shorter lambda solution (***-73***)
Thanks to @thedefault. for using the `..` operator and `Convert.ToByte` (***-10***)</sup>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYyxCsIwEIb3PMXRqYE2NF1EagsquDkpOIhDiKkEagK9a6FInz2mxc2DO35@vu805hp1GNC6F1wmJPOumO4UIuzhwwCQFFkNo7dPOCvrUr7W8IPFaXB6h9RHPwPrqIEW6oB1c/RuND2Jqz9MZFK8SyG2j6zkuSw3oVp/RAZ9Z8SttxFp06QoZJzlLOlvZcL5Ys5sDl8)

**As it turns out, C# is actually quite useful for golfing! Lambdas are the way to go!**

---

Welcome to code golf, Maximilian Rose!

Comment: C# does lambdas, right? That would save on all the I/O overhead at least.

Comment: C# does have lambdas, but I tried them and the byte count did not decrease. (I am quite new to lambdas though,  so maybe I had done something wrong)

Comment: Yeah, I would have to look through some other C# answers to see how to use them properly to save bytes.

Comment: You can actually substantially decrease it using lambdas ([42 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZYzBCoJAEIbvPsXgaRd0ce1QYAoRBB06GXS2bZUF24WdUYjw2Te1bg3M8PPzfaMwVc7rMKCxHdQvJP0sItU3iHCAdwSA1JBRMDrzgEtjLONrDT9YnAar9kh@9hMwlipooQxYVkdnR@1JXN3Z0iZnKOrh/gWZTHY8yXkq820o1m8zja7X4uYNadayOMvkPMtZ0t/KmPPFnKIpfAA)). You also had a few spaces here and there.

Comment: @user Welp, too bad I could not find that solution. Nice job!

Comment: Well, you're now beating Retina...

Comment: 33 bytes by changing the compiler and using a range: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZUzBCsIwFLvvKx47tbCVtR5E5gYiCB48KXgQD6N2Upgt9L0NRPbtdRveDCSEkERjrlHHHq17wvmNZF5lorsGEXbwSQCQGrIaBm8fcGqsY3yJ4VcWh97pLVKY9hlYRzW0UEWs6r13gwkkLv7oaKUY3qQQm3umeC7VOpbLyVRC3xlxDZYMa1laFHLCLLP7o0w5n5djMsYv "C# (Visual C# Compiler) – Try It Online"). I also think you can use Convert.ToByte instead of Convert.ToInt32.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 30 bytes

```
r~8[01:@{2%*+$2*60l4)?.{""-n;
```

(contains an unprintable `DEL` between the quotes)

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v6jOItrA0Mqh2khVS1vFSMvUIMdE016vWqleSTfP@v///7rFBgaGQAAiQCwMbAgA)

```
r~8[                           grab relevant part of string
    01                         accumulator and exponent initialization
                             main loop
       @{2%                    convert current digit charcter to 0 and 1
           *+$                 accumulate     
      :       2*               increment exponent
                60l4)?.        loop while digits remaining
                       {""-n;  print result sub 127 and terminate
```

Most of the work is constructing a number from binary notation.

Answer (score 3):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 49 bytes

```forth
: b drop 1+ 8 ['] evaluate 2 base-execute 127 - ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WykkKaQU5RcoGGorWChEq8cqpJYl5pQmlqQqGCkkJRan6qZWpCaXArmGRuYKugrW/4uVFAwMDIEARIBYGNhQCWio3n8A)

Done using (a lot of) Bubbler's help.

Forth has one(1) convenient command that allows interpretation of strings as binary, and that's used here(`base-execute`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>11</s> 6 bytes

```
9ŻB⁺ɽ-
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=9%C5%BBB%E2%81%BA%C9%BD-&inputs=00111101110011001100110011001101&header=&footer=)

I've got an advantage that y'all don't have: I actually sat the exam this question is based upon as well at the same time as the OP (#hsc_gang #option_topic_2 #ir_sw_hw). Hopefully I got both that question and this answer right!

### Explained

```
9ŻB⁺ɽ-
9Ż      #     input[1:9]
  B     # int(          , 2)
   ⁺ɽ   #                      127 (N.B. Pushes the index of ɽ in the codepage + 101)
     -  #                    -
        # int(input[1:9], 2) - 127
```

**Update**: Turns out I got the wrong answer in the exam. Not pog.

Comment: finally, a challenge where Vyxal doesn't smash everything in

Comment: No tail operator or prefix slicing!? (Or, a built-in for 127.)

Comment: @Razetime what were you saying?

Comment: *b   r   u   h m o m e n t o*

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 43 bytes

```rust
|s|Ok(i32::from_str_radix(&s[1..9],2)?-127)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYyxCsIwFEV3vyJ2kATaklRBjFonByfFVaQEmkCxTfG9FATrt9fE4qIP3uUO9xzo0A3GkkZVlrInqbUjRhpLZ@iAJflZY1e7TTXPYnSllLZrpDwpQH2wbg/QQk62Q4/98Ub9SEoDbVN4tgBVVg@vuYg0XV3jjO0SkS3ZsJ4oRA2u0PcpNTTiXPgLEdrfi4jF3p0sGPslP5D40j5GCQ8lxEjyAL6GNw)

Returns a `Result<i32,ParseIntError>`. I would have loved to use an `i8` instead of an `i32` but that would panic if the leading bit is 1.

Comment: Is there no `u8` type?

Comment: @Neil there is an i8 type but the code will panic if `s[1] == 1`

Comment: ... I didn't ask about `i8`?

Comment: @Neil There is a `u8` type but I would have to cast it into a different type to prevent underflow if `s[1] == 0`, and casts are lots of bytes

Comment: Oh, right, it will try to do an unsigned subtraction? I guess I'm too used to C's default int promotion. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Neil Precisely. The `u8` type is an unsigned byte and only goes from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>174</s> <s>113</s> 111 bytes

<sup>-61 bytes for many optimizations</sup>

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to RezNesX</sup>

```
,>++++++++>>--[>-<--]>-<<<[>,>>>[--<+>]<[->+<]<-[<->-----]<+++[->>>[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<<<<<]<-]>>>>---[>-<--]>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCoRQDEMP9H8G3YdcpHQxCoIILgTP/yeFwY2BhpK@Zrm@@7nd6zFGV/tLAkIgkHYy1CUFwKZkQI1JBGHOSvrHaSFqPjJrpWnjJdOOqvbp/YwxTbNVVttr5h8)

Input is 32 bits taken one at a time.

Explanation:

```
,> first bit garbage
++++++++ set cur cell (cell 2) to 8
>>--[>-<--]>-<<< set cell 5 to 128 (so the first division moves it over)

[> do 8 times

, input to cell 3

>>> cell 6
[--<+>] div 2 to 5
<[->+<] move back to 6
< cell 4

-[<->-----]<+++ convert to bin value (sub 48) using cell 4

[- if 1 (in cell 3)
>>>[->+>+<<] add cell 6 into cell 7 & 8
>>[-<<+>>] move cell 8 back to 6
<<<<<
]

<-] ends on c2

>>>> to c6 (has 1 and next cell has value)

---[>-<--]> sub 127
. outputs final answer (as ASCII= if this is invalid let me know)
```

Comment: [111 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCoRQDEMP9H8G3YdcpHQxCoIILgTP/yeFwY2BhpK@Zrm@@7nd6zFGV/tLAkIgkHYy1CUFwKZkQI1JBGHOSvrHaSFqPjJrpWnjJdOOqvbp/YwxTbNVVttr5h8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
Ḋḣ8Ḅ_127
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjq6HOxZbPNzREm9oZP7//38DHQMdQyg0gNMGRNKGAA)

Takes input as a list of digits

### How it works

```
Ḋḣ8Ḅ_127 - Main link. Takes a list of bits B on the left
Ḋ        - Dequeue; Remove the first element of B
 ḣ8      - Take the first 8 elements
   Ḅ     - Convert from binary
    _127 - Subtract 127
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 11 bytes

```
-127+2/8#1_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NStfQyFzbSN9C2TD@f5qCARAaQqEBnDYgkjb8DwA)

```
         1_        drop one
       8#          take 8
     2/            to binary
-127+              subtract 127
```

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 14 bytes

Just an experiment - a port of [Lynn's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214774/75681)

```
{y-1+2*x}/8#1_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqrpS11DbSKuiVt9C2TD@f5qCARAaQqEBnDYgkjb8DwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 31 bytes

```
~$7v@.-1-~'$$<
_1->\2*~2%+\#^:!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@vUzEvc9DTNdStU1dRseGKN9S1izHSqjNS1Y5RjrNS/P/fwMAQCEAEiIWBDQE)

---

#### Animation

[image]

#### Explanation

`~$7v` is the initialization code:
`~$` read and discard the first character
`7` push initial value of the loop counter
`v` redirect the instruction pointer down

The second line is the main loop, since `>` is the entry point it is executed as `\2*~2%+\#^:!_1-` from left to right. Initially the loop counter is on top of the stack and the current result on the second position:
`\` swap to the current exponent value
`2*` double it
`~` read the next digits
`2%` modulo `2` maps `'0'` to `0` and `'1'` to `1`
`+` add to the current result
`\` swap to the loop counter
`#` skips the the command (`^`)
`:!` duplicate the loop counter and boolean negate the copy

If the value on the top of the stack is now falsey (loop counter was `>0`), `_` lets the IP move east and the main loop continues by subtracing `1` from the loop counter (`1-`). Otherwise the IP moves west and executes the following:

```
    @.-1-~'$$<
_            ^:!
```

By removing the IP movement commands and writing everything from left to right, this results in `!:$$'~-1-.@`:
`!` invert the loop counter again
`:$$` duplicate the value and pop both copies
`'~-` subtract `'~' = 126`
`1-.` subract `1` and print
`@` terminate the program

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 27 bytes

```perl
/.(.{8})/;$_=-127+oct"0b$1"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fT0Ov2qJWU99aJd5W19DIXDs/uUTJIEnFUOn/fwMDQyAAESAWBjbkAssZwhQBCYhaAxADRPzLLyjJzM8r/q@bUwAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 58 bytes

```
import strutils
echo stdin.readAll[1..8].fromBin[:int]-127
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/M7cgv6hEobikqLQkM6eYKzU5Ix/IS8nM0ytKTUxxzMmJNtTTs4jVSyvKz3XKzIu2yswridU1NDL//9/AwBAIQASIhYENAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
Ｉ⁻⍘Φ…Ｓ⁹κ²¦¹²⁷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzczr7RYwymxODW4BCiaruGWmVOSWqThXJmck@qckV@g4ZlXUFoCldTUUbAE4mwgNgJiQyNzTU1N6///DQwMgQBEgFgY2PC/blkOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
     Ｓ          Input string
    … ⁹         Take first 9 characters
   Φ   κ        Remove first character
  ⍘     ²       Convert from base 2
 ⁻        ¹²⁷   Subtract 127
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>26</s>  24 bytes

```javascript
x=>'0b'+x.slice(1,9)-127
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1k7dIEldu0KvOCczOVXDUMdSU9fQyPx/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoa6gYEhEIAIEAsDG6prav4HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
［］９＠ｊ｛┤］２┴‾p－
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNCJXVGRjNEJXVGRjE5JXVGRjIwJXVGRjRBJXVGRjVCJXUyNTI0JXVGRjNEJXVGRjEyJXUyNTM0JXUyMDNFcCV1RkYwRA__,i=JTIyMDAxMTExMDExMTAwMTEwMDExMDAxMTAwMTEwMDExMDElMjI_,v=8)

### Explanation

```
[]9@j{⊣]2⊥¯p⊣-
[]              get all prefixes
  9@            9th prefix
    j           remove first element
     {⊣]        cast each element to integer
        2⊥      decode from base 2
          ¯p    127
            -   subtract that from it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Note the unprintable (charcode 127) at the end.

```
Å¯8 Í-#
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=xa84IM0tI38&input=IjAwMTExMTAxMTEwMDExMDAxMTAwMTEwMDExMDAxMTAxIg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 121 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S S S T    T   T   N
_Push_7][S N
S _Duplicate_7][T   N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][S S S T    T   S S S S N
Push_48][T  S S T   _Subtract][S T  S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd][S S S T  S N
_Push_2][T  S S N
_Multiply][T    S S S _Add][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S S S T  N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   T   S N
_If_negative_Jump_to_Label_PRINT_RESULT][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT_RESULT][S N
N
_Discard_top][S S S T   T   T   T   T   T   T   N
_Push_127][T    S S T   _Subtract][T    N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##ZU1JCoBADDs3r@gTZp4kMqA3QcHnd5IoXiw0XZI297Zf4zyWdVRlJpgRATaB0IgHNJEwnRISuRH4xgt8lPXmQD1YAL/H66CwhF5R1VpnCNT9sk8) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer r = 0
Integer n = 7
Read STDIN as character
Start LOOP:
  Integer c = STDIN as character
  c = c - 48
  r = r * 2
  r = c + r
  n = n - 1
  If(n < 0):
    Jump to label PRINT_RESULT
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

PRINT_RESULT:
  r = r - 127
  Print r as integer to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
-127ḋ↑8t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X9fQyPzhju5HbRMtSv7//x9toGOgYwiFBnDagEjaMBYA)

Straightforward implementation following the steps of the question.  Accepts list of digits as argument.

```
-127ḋ↑8t
       t        # tail: remove first element
     ↑8         # get first 8 remaining elements
    ḋ           # interpret as binary digits
-127            # subtract 127
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), 25 bytes

```julia
n->parse("0b"*n[2:9])-127
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsMgEEDRdT3FkNVYGlFLCSk0y14iZGGCFoto0On5ra7@5vG/v@DNVB28oMZxOU0uFge5D9e46ue88VHpqZIt1MTuqVD28SPwHZKhuxa4sosU6gY9@tGrhGQb54ydjVKIAo8Ugj0I22MBh8TBpQwEPkI/N1v/)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 40 bytes

```cs
Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(1,8),2)-127;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/F9cUpSZl65QrGCroGRgYAgEIALEwsCGStZcZYlFCkWpxaU5JQq2/53z88pSi0r0QvI980qMjTSK9YJLkyAGahjqWGjqGGnqGhqZW4MUFufnpOqFF2WWpPpk5qVq5CXmpuanaUCM0lTQVlC3UgeRCiASKmr9HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Zsh, 20 bytes

```bash
<<<$[0b${n:1:8}-127]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@ekZmTqlCUmpiikJOZl2qtkJLPVZxaoqCrq6ACEuDKs1Ux/G9jY6MSbZCkUp1nZWhlUatraGQe@z8lPy/1v4GBIRCACBALAxtygeUMYYqABEStAYgBIrgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḣ8ɱḂṇȷ-
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCVBMzglQzklQjElRTElQjglODIlRTElQjklODclQzglQjctJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JTIyMDAxMTExMDExMTAwMTEwMDExMDAxMTAwMTEwMDExMDElMjImZmxhZ3M9ZQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
ḣ8ɱḂṇȷ-  # Implicit input
ḣ        # Remove first item
 8ɱ      # Next 8 characters
   Ḃ     # Convert from binary
    ṇȷ-  # Subtract 127
         # Implicit output
```