# Generating versions of an array with elements changed in ruby

Tags: code-golf, tips, ruby

I'm new to code golf challenges. My problem came up in [Advent of Code 2020 Day 8](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/8)

The input is an array of arrays. In part two of the problem one needs to run several trials to produce a result by changing an element in the input array. My current code is this (comments added to explain what's going on):

```ruby
p input.each_with_index { |val, i|
  next if val[0] != :acc # not all elements need to be experimented with
  changed = input.dup # clone input to make a change
  # change the first element of the value at input position i (but keep the rest)
  changed[i] = val.dup.tap { |v| v[0] = v[0] == :nop ? :jmp : :nop }
  result = try_with(changed) # run the experiment
  break result if result[1] == :terminate # success condition
end
```

So, that's quite a lot of code for something relatively simple. Can I make it shorter? Can I have a simple generator that produces different versions of the same array?

My complete code for day 8 is [here](https://paste.ofcode.org/RfLdnvUqxWbRiz7EyFxN2Y)

**Edit:**

As suggested in the comments, I'll try to put the problem my snippet is solving as a code golf challenge (note that this is just my snippet):

In ruby you have `input`: an array of instructions. Each element of `input` is another array of two elements, where the first is a symbol (the instruction name) which is one three: `:acc`, `:jmp`, or `:nop`, and the second is an integer (the instruction argument).

You also have a function `try_with` which works with such an array, executes the instructions and returns `[n, :terminate]` if the program terminates or `[n, :loop]` if the program is an endless loop. `n` is the value of the accumulator after the execution.

The original input is a loop. If you change *one* of the instructions in the input array from `:nop` to `:jmp` **or** from `:jmp` to `:nop`, and keep the argument, it will result in a terminating program. What is the value of the accumulator after you find and execute the terminating program?

**The original AOC2008D8 problem**

You have a file with valid assembly. Each line is a three character instruction and a (possibly negative) integer argument separated by a single space. Example

```
nop +0
acc +1
jmp +4
acc +3
jmp -3
acc -99
acc +1
jmp -4
acc +6
```

Instructions are `acc` add arg to accumulator and increment ip, `jmp` add arg to ip, `nop` ignore arg and just increment ip.

Then... what I said above about the snippet-only problem

Changing the next-to-last line in the example from `jmp` to `nop` results in a termination with acc value: 8

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! You may also want to check out [tips for golfing in ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby).

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Could you state the problem the code is intended to solve in English along with how IO should be handled?  Putting this in English rather than in code is ideal because often golfing can slightly change the behavior in acceptable ways, e.g. use more memory or time, and it is unclear what is acceptable from a code snippet alone.  Plus English is just easier to understand a lot of the time.

Comment: @WheatWizard sure. Do you mean the AOC2020D8 problem or to try to put just the problem my snippet is solving as a code golf challenge?

Comment: I added a detailed description of the problem in a "human" language :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <sup><s>102</s> <s>99</s> <s>98</s></sup> 95 bytes

```ruby
(k=input.map &:dup)[$.-=1][0]=%i[nop jmp acc][k[$.][0]<=>:jmp]until(r=try_with k||$:)[1]>:t;p r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJhb4IwEP3ur7hkboMoROKyRBT3Q5pm6aCETixNKTMu/nd2V2Ri4gfSd3fv3r32sN3XuS9kCc6eP0/KVYEIZwAizyGDFSJlrqBSrWvsGSPGMaybxkDRIALIRStBMGU4W3GfOVVSQ0oqjhCBRXalJHxLqhgnE@730QzcoTRSJwzd3DGGZqkLf6pyNBgrndddIT8CZUJ4gpN8/ZHIc9LKAoQ37lsArHSd1cDQ3hJSKgzzZN2iHt0cjcSt@pX/OlaKvEIdNEKzoSk9VLp1tsudanT7UBynH5UWTvI72@Oj7nY4bjbk6ZspbTpHb83o3ktYrPgSWOrFFonH@GKI3yb59S0frW/5aLN53BxNm98574ND5gfHR2HgJS06E7J5HGUJLTZ7Vox2QJvCFs4OWKPCLtuTHu@0U3Vgs/FXgsPlMk9D3OI@dVsDtu//AA)

I assume that `input` and `try_with` are mandatory names for the Advent of Code challenge. If not, the code can obviously be even shorter. Here, I also assume that the `try_with` method will accept invalid input, that is, an array whose elements are not of the form `[:instruction, integer]`. See below for a slightly longer version in case `try_with` strictly requires valid input.

See commented code below for a complete list of ideas used. Apart from generic code-golf tips such as 'use short variable names', or common Ruby tips such as 'omit parentheses in method calls', here are some specific tips for the problem posed:

- Instead of `each_with_index`, use a counter variable <s>together with an anonymous lambda and `redo`</s> together with `until` (or `while`) in modifier form. For the counter, a good choice in this case is the predefined global variable `$.`, which is initialised to `0`. Processing the `input` array in reverse (by decrementing `$.` in place) is the best approach. Incrementing `$.` in place doesn't work (because `input[0]` would be skipped); incrementing `$.` at the end of the loop would cost bytes.
- Only call `dup` at the lowest level, that is, on the elements of `input`, not on `input` itself.
- Lexicographical comparisons work with symbols, so `>:t` is better than `== :terminate`, for example.
- It turns out to be slightly shorter to use the spaceship operator `<=>` instead of a ternary conditional to choose between instructions. In the code, `k[$.][0]<=>:jmp` returns `-1` if the current instruction is `:acc`, `0` if it is `:jmp`, and `1` if it is `:nop`. Use these values to index into an array of the three symbols, ordered such that the correct replacement is chosen.

```ruby
(k=                # use parentheses to define variables inline
   input.map &:dup # only duplicate the lowest-level arrays, and do all at once
)[$.-=1][0]        # use $. as a counter and decrement in place                       
=%i[nop jmp acc][k[$.][0]<=>:jmp] # use the spaceship operator to choose between instructions            
until              # loop with until
(r=try_with k      # omit parentheses in the call to try_with
||$:)[1]           # on the first iteration (only), k is nil so pass the predefined array $: to try_with as dummy input
>:t;               # test for >:t instead of ==:terminate
p r                # print the result
```

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 98 bytes

```ruby
p->{(k=input.map &:dup)[$.-=1][0]=%i[nop jmp acc][k[$.][0]<=>:jmp];(r=try_with k)[1]>:t||redo;r}[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLtbsIwDPzPU1jaVytoRcU0iULZg0TRlLVBzYAkStMhNvbsnZ2uo0j8qHKxz@eLXde@n7pKbsG709tR@ToS8QRAlCUUMEek7B@oVeONO@GNcbzujbFQGUQApWgkCKYsZ3MeIsdaashJxRMiMC3@KBlfkSresxH342B7bp8aqCOGNleMvljqKpxqOxhMlS73bSVfI2VjuIOjfPqUyPPSyQpEMB5KAJz0rdPA0N4Mckr0/eS@QT16ORpJG/Ul/3WcFGWNOmiEeoPZBqh0411bemV0c1Mcux@UFl7yK9vDUNdrbDfp4/RNlLatp1kzevcMpnM@A5YHsWkWME4M8fMovrjEk8UlniyXt4uTcfEL551NNt/RrgjN04Ow8JhXrY3ZfZoUGS23eFCM9kDbwjLOdpijxLrYkCZfRa4YfiXYxbjBTe7PZxy9WbkfxrvuFw)

Use this version if `try_with` rejects `$:` as valid input. Here, we iterate using an anonymous lambda and `redo`.