# Create a nibble shorthand

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, binary, open-ended-function

I recently stumbled across [this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tesseract_Hasse_diagram_with_nibble_shorthands.svg) on wikimedia commons.  It's a little bit of an information overload at first, but after examining it a bit it shows an interesting number system for writing nibbles.

[image: Tesseract Hasse diagram with nibble shorthands]

*Image created by user [Watchduck](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Watchduck).*

First off a "nibble" is a 4 bit number which is really a number ranging from 0 to 15, with a particular emphasis on binary.  This diagram shows a shorthand for writing such numbers with each number being one symbol. Ok, who cares? Plenty of people make up new symbols for numbers all the time.  Well the interesting thing about these numbers is their symmetry.

If you take one of the symbols and mirror it horizontally you get the symbol of the number with the same bits in reverse order.  For example the symbol that sort of looks like a 3 represents the bits 0011, it's horizontal mirror represents the bits 1100. Numbers which are symmetric along this mirror represent nibbles which are palindromes.

Similarly if you take a symbol and rotate it a half turn (180 degrees) you get the symbol for the bitwise compliment of that number, for example if you take the symbol that looks like a 7, it represents 0111, if you rotate it a half turn you get a symbol representing 1000.

### Task

You will write a program or function which takes as input a nibble and outputs an image of a symbol. Your symbols are not required to be anything in specific but they are required to have the symmetry properties.

1. Distinct nibbles should give distinct symbols
2. The symbol for a nibble \$r\$ should be the mirror image of the symbol for the reverse of \$r\$.
3. The symbol for a nibble \$r\$ should be the symbol for the bitwise compliment of \$r\$ rotated 180 degrees.

You may take input in any reasonable format and output in any image or graphical format.  There are no additional requirements on resolution, aside from those implied by the rules.  You can make your symbols as small as you wish as long as you satisfy the rules.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

Comment: Are Unicode characters (such as the ones from the [Geometric Shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes_(Unicode_block)) block) a valid/reasonable output format for this challenge?

Comment: @Arnauld [That's a forbidden loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12155/)

Comment: How characters are rendered is entirely up to the font in use.  Is `p` the mirror image of `q`?  It depends on the font. You can maybe say an answer in X language + Y font satisfies the requirement, but at that point it would really just be making a programming language to trivialize the problem.  The challenge is [tag:graphical-output] that's what it's about.

Comment: So, to be clear, text output is entirely forbidden unless it's part of an image?

Comment: Can the nibble be taken as a binary array with 4 digits? That is, `[0 0 1 1]` for `3`

Comment: @LuisMendo Sure.

Comment: It looks like you stumbled upon a way to summon a computer daemon.

Answer (score 18):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>12</s> 7 bytes

```
t~Pv1YG
```

Input is a 4-digit binary vector.

**Example outputs** (or try it at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=t%7EPv1YG&inputs=%5B0+1+0+0%5D&version=22.7.4)!):

- Input `[0 1 0 0]`:

[image]

- Input `[1 0 1 1]`:

[image]

- Input `[1 1 0 1]`:

[image]

- Input `[1 0 0 1]`:

[image]

- Input `[0 1 1 0]`:

[image]

#### How it works

The output is a 2-row, 4-column image where the first row corresponds to the input binary digits, and the second row is the first element-wise negated and reversed.

```
t     % Implicit input. Duplicate
      % STACK: [0 1 0 0], [0 1 0 0]
~     % Negate, element-wise
      % STACK: [0 1 0 0], [1 0 1 1]
P     % Reverse
      % STACK: [0 1 0 0], [1 1 0 1]
v     % Vertically concatenate
      % STACK: [0 1 0 0; 1 1 0 1]
1YG   % Display image with scaled colors. 0 is shown as black, 1 as white
```

Comment: Both 0000 and 1111 are just a horizontal bar. Both 0011 and 1100 are just a square. Yes, they are in different positions in regard to a background grid, so the answer is formally correct. But would you accept them as distinct "characters" if this was a script?

Comment: @ccprog All inputs produce a 2x4 image. There is no background, just a 2x4 image in which each of the 8 pixels is either black or white

Comment: Yes, there is no grid. What I meant is that you would need one to securely distinguish between the symbols. Imagine using these images to write the hex number sequences `5BA` and `A35`. Would you be able to read them correctly? Again, this was not part of the question, but I wonder if there are solutions that combine your algorithmic simplicity with the visual clearness of Jordan's answer.

Comment: @ccprog You would have to define how to arrange the images for a _sequence_ of inputs. If you stack them, say, vertically, the two sequences you mention give [this](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L@kLqDsv0vI/2gDBUMFII7ligbTSCyDWAA) and [this](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L@kLqDsv0vI/2hDBQMFII7lijYAswzBLLBoLAA), using `0` and `1` to denote black and white pixels respectively. Those two 6x4 images are different. So what's the confusion? (Honest question, just trying to understand your argument). What do you mean by "symbols" exactly?

Comment: Oh, oh, the first one should have been `5CA` (blush), and I was assuming horizontal stacking and a distance between the individual parts, just as if the single images were digits from a font. If you stack vertically, the distinction between `0` and `F` would be the one difficult to read. Key point: in a longer vertical sequence, would you be able to see if the line sits low or high, and in a horizontal sequence, if the square (or the two short vertical lines of 5 and C) sits left or right? - I use "symbol" just as in the question, image = symbol ( = glyph, if you prefer the typografical term).

Comment: @ccprog I think I see what you mean: “reading” a sequence of  individual images as if they were letters read by a person. Then yes, I agree that more discernible symbols (individual images) would be preferred. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 106 bytes

Takes an integer as input and returns a PBM image.

```ruby
->i{t="'/%[g|eS	
smR\rzrt"
"P1
5 3
"+("%08b"%t[t.index(i.chr)+1].ord).gsub(/./,'\&0')[1..]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3s3TtMqtLbJUYxBnVmfSZVVmiWdPZathTOYI55bmKuXN5gmKKqviK-EuUuJQCDLlMFYy5lLQ1lFQNLJKUVEuiS_Qy81JSKzQy9ZIzijS1DWP18otSNPXSi0uTNPT19HXUY9QM1DWjDfX0YmuhNsZoGOjpGZpq6qUmJmcopOQr1OTVcCkoZOYmpqcq2CqkRefFArkFpSXFCkrWCqnJGfkKMUrK1WD52hglBTsF5Wqg_SZA-_Nq9QqScpWgyrlS81IgdixYAKEB)

The code has unprintable characters that make it copy-and-paste-unfriendly; expand the below snippet for an xxd dump if you want to try it on your own machine.

```html
00000000: 2d3e 697b 743d 2200 1701 2702 2f03 2504  ->i{t="...'./.%.
00000010: 5b05 6706 7c07 6508 5309 1f0a 730b 6d0c  [.g.|.e.S...s.m.
00000020: 525c 727a 0e72 0f74 220a 2250 310a 3520  R\rz.r.t"."P1.5 
00000030: 330a 222b 2822 2530 3862 2225 745b 742e  3."+("%08b"%t[t.
00000040: 696e 6465 7828 692e 6368 7229 2b31 5d2e  index(i.chr)+1].
00000050: 6f72 6429 2e67 7375 6228 2f2e 2f2c 2726  ord).gsub(/./,'&
00000060: 3027 295b 312e 2e5d 7d0a                 0')[1..]}.
```

### The shorthand

[image]

### How it works

The images are 5×3 but there are only 7 "real" pixels, in a hex pattern:

```
 1 1
1 1 1
 1 1
```

This makes each image's data fit in a byte. `t` is a lookup table where the ASCII character corresponding to each nibble is followed by the character corresponding to its image representation. The code looks up the image data in the table, formats it as a string of `1`s and `0`s, interleaves the extra `0`s, and returns it in PBM format.

### Ungolfed

```ruby
->input{
  table = "\x00\x17\x01\x27\x02\x2f\x03\x25\x04\x5b\x05\x67\x06\x7c\x07\x65\x08\x53\x09\x1f\x0a\x73\x0b\x6d\x0c\x52\x0d\x7a\x0e\x72\x0f\x74"
  image_byte = table[table.index(input.chr) + 1].ord
  image_data = ("%08b" % image_byte).gsub(/./,'\&0')[1..]

  "P1
5 3
" + image_data
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3) + [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) and [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), <s>101</s> <s>92</s> <s>91</s> <s>82</s> 77 bytes

```python
import numpy as n,PIL.Image as p
lambda x:p.fromarray(n.array([x,1-x[::-1]]))
```

Takes in a NumPy array of ones and zeros and returns the resulting 4x2 image. Basically a copy of [Luis Mendo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252262/114332) in Python.
Ungolfed:

```python
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def represent(nibble: np.array) -> None:
    representation = np.array([nibble, 1 - nibble[::-1])
    image = Image.fromarray(representation)
    return image
```

Thanks to Louis Mendo, who figured this out (and then saved me 9 bytes)!

Examples:

- `[1, 0, 0, 1]`

[image: first example]

- `[1, 1, 1, 1]`

[image: second example]

- `[0, 1, 1, 0]`

[image: third example]

I have no idea where the blurring comes from. However, it still satisfies the criteria. Note that in these images, the colors are RGB (0, 0, 0) and (255, 255, 255), for human readability. However, in the image generated by the program, the colors are (0, 0, 0) and (1, 1, 1), which, while distinct, cannot be told appart using a human eye.

- -9 thanks to Luis Mendo
- -1 thanks to Jonathan Allen
- -9 because I figured out I could return the image instead of displaying it, and not assign this to a variable
- -5 again thanks to Jonathan Allen

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks, that reduces the code by 9 bytes

Comment: `(1-x)[::-1]` -> `-~-x[::-1]` (yep `-` and `~` should work with NumPy arrays).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks. I'd originally tried `~x` instead of `1-x` but Python's bitwise not (annoyingly) works with unsigned integers.

Comment: ...oh, hang on, you can just do `1-x[::-1]` :)

Comment: I wonder if you really need the `255*` too?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks. Initially, when I was writing this, I got an almost all black image, because the values were (0, 0, 0) and (1, 1, 1) instead of (255, 255, 255). So for human readability - yes, but for machine exactness, no.

Comment: The blurring is Pillow's default approach when scaling up an image. I believe you can get rid of it by passing a keyword argument `resample=Image.Dither.NONE` to the `resize` function (assuming that's how you're enlarging the image).

Comment: The blurring looks like a scaling algorithm like bilinear or something more sophisticated that weights based on multiple neighbouring pixels, not just "nearest" which would make large black squares with sharp edges.  In most images, the squareness of pixels is a downside, an artifact of digital sampling of a continuous image, not something to be preserved.  Pixel art is different, which is why emulators for old computers and game consoles typically have options for upscaling with algorithms like 2xSAI.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel-art_scaling_algorithms

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (browser), <s>187</s> 182 bytes

```js
f=
(n,c)=>c.getContext`2d`.putImageData(new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(Int32Array.from([...s=n.toString(2).padStart(4,0),...[...s].reverse()],(c,i)=>-1<<(c^i/4)*24).buffer),4),0,0)
```

```css
canvas{width:256px;height:128px;image-rendering:pixelated;}
```

```html
<input type=number size=2 min=0 max=15 oninput=f(+this.value,c)><div><canvas id=c height=2 width=4>
```

Uses @LuisMendo's method. Draws the output on a `2×4` canvas passed as the second parameter, but the snippet scales the output up 64 times for convenience.

Comment: You're missing the negation step for the second 4.

Comment: you can curry the function with `n=>c=>` instead of `(n,c)=>` for -1

Comment: @ccprog Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @thejonymyster see first comment.

Comment: I find it a bit dishonest not to count the HTML and CSS bytes.

Comment: @ccprog Functions may output by modifying their arguments.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 23 bytes

A port of [@Luis Mendo's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252262/9288).

```
Image@{#,Reverse[1-#]}&
```

[image]

Comment: `Image@{#,1-Reverse@#}&` saves one byte. If we represented the bits as -1 and 1 rather than 0 and 1, then we could do `Image@{#,-Reverse@#}&`, but that might be bending the rules somewhat.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
142D;Ṛ;¬K”P;
```

A full program that outputs a PBM file on STD OUT.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUAAv/9qZWxsef//MTQyRDvhuZo7wqxL4oCdUDv/MuG4tuG5lzTCtcOH4oG@IiJqLEDFkuG5mGrigJwgLT4g4oCdKVn/)**

#### How?

Jelly cannot produce images on screen, so this places an image file content on STD OUT ready to be directed to a file.

The PBM format idea came from [Jordan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11261/jordan)'s [Goruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252279/53748) and [Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252278/53748) posts. Go upvote!

The method is similar to [Luis Meno](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)'s [MATL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252262/53748) post, because there is nothing simpler. Go upvote!

The only difference is that rather than the number on top of the reversed negated number we have the reverse of the number on top of the negated number.

```
142D;Ṛ;¬K”P; - Main Link: list of four bits, N     e.g. [0,0,1,0]
142          - 142
   D         - to decimal digits -> [1, 4, 2]
     Ṛ       - reverse (N)                              [0,1,0,0]
    ;        - concatenate                              [1,4,2,0,1,0,0]
       ¬     - logical NOT (N)                          [1,1,0,1]
      ;      - concatenate                              [1,4,2,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]
        K    - join with spaces                         [1,' ',4,' ',2,' ',0,' ',1,' ',0,' ',0,' ',1,' ',1,' ',0,' ',1]
         ”P  - 'P'
           ; - concatenate                              ['P',1,' ',4,' ',2,' ',0,' ',1,' ',0,' ',0,' ',1,' ',1,' ',0,' ',1]
             - implicit, smashing print                 P1 4 2 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
                                                        i.e. the pixels:
                                                        0100
                                                        1101
```

Answer (score 3):

### HTML + Javascript 70 + <s>159</s> <s>154</s> 151 = 221 bytes

The output is topologically like [Jordan's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252258/252278), with the output rotated by 90° and lines instead of dots. This achieves a classical seven part display. The symbols also loosely resemble those used by Watchduck in his original grafic in shape and order.

The order of the elements is

```
  0            M1,1h3
1   2      M1,1v3  M4,1v3
  3             M1,4h3
4   5      M1,4v3  M4,4v3
  6            M1,7h3
```

After experimenting with multiple other variants, I find it interesting that this intuitive ordering still gives the shortest path production.

The Bigint holds the shown elements for each symbol as bits ordered right to left. Since the symbol for 1111, the last symbol, has no shown elements in the lower half, the last (leftmost) hex digit is 0, and the number can be written in hex with 27 digits instead of the expected 16*7/4 = 28.

*-5 bytes thanks to Steffan.*

*-3 bytes for bitwise operation on `BigInt` and symbol reordering.*

```js
f=n=>{for(d='',i=0;i<7;i++)0xe5cfdb4f4dbf24fdb2f2dbf3a70n>>BigInt(n*7+i)&1n?d+=`M${(i+1)%3?1:4},${(i/3&3)*3+1}${i%3?'v':'h'}3`:0;p.setAttribute('d',d)}
```

```html
<input oninput=f(value)><svg viewBox=0,0,5,8><path id=p stroke=#000 />
```

#### Ungolfed and a bit more pretty

```js
f = n => {
    t = 0xe5cfdb4f4dbf24fdb2f2dbf3a70n
    for (d='',i=0; i<7; i++) {
        if (t>>BigInt(n*7+i)&1n) {
            d += `M${(i+1)%3?1:4},${(i/3&3)*3+1}${i%3?'v':'h'}3`
        }
    }
    p.setAttribute('d', d)
}
f(0)
```

```html
<input type=number size=2 value=0 min=0 max=15 oninput=f(value)>
<div>
  <svg viewBox=0,0,5,8 width=80>
    <path id=p stroke=#000 />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to convert `0xca9d787f8ded97e9b7b1fe1eb953n.toString(2)` to a list. (aka remove `[...` and `]`)

Answer (score 2):

## [Goruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby/9289#9289), 37 bytes

Takes an array of `0`s and `1`s and returns a PBM image.

Same technique as [Luis Mendo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252262/11261).

```ruby
->a{"P1
4 2
#{a+a.rv.m{_1>0?0:1}}"}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pVbdbts2FL73U5w4aSw5imJvHTAEddN2SLfdrEML7GKGJ1ASbbOVKJWk3NiS8iK7ycX2AHuc7Wl2SEryT92iw3IR0uf_5zuH-v0PUYTrh39670_h-0zfIRc0KeJelBAp4VX4lkaqB_Ds2SJL5sGSyCVMoKx7SFtREWaSenD2y-3rF6_e3CKnvXrAWYIyMZ1DStUyi4OUScn4AlIPhsSD8xDZAAqVdoxPYYp8SZO5byKYwQyqagIpUdEStQNrTDqpOx3NjAU2RyPn52DtAQSBpDwOAkdpRy6U1ZCIhawaNkDoh4zHaMynK5I4_VxkUVmZEIybmChSwdk9RrZPhLrv-hFJEufs3tV-z-53jBqGceU21NqcNJG0ISi4OQhP18GFa5BFToUV53Gv_b9T2KbYvbamh_WQKDMYeJDiqSMhYUJbpo1HIOfqt9NS-ioLpL-QRehc-Vdu2Xf84Y3bhwt4TRf0LvepjEhOnbNzt66vjG7qLwTNHeH6MhMqQJjEGVSsrSmzJk1QWgjVVSGopuTO-bVkG-rCkyfADjJskrHtzrhUHUiiT4Aj8r4AG5EHxhrhSnYwUUB4DIJiYNyygwVVjmqKQ5ik8BNJ6a0QmfCgX3DGmWIkweDjzh6cllHd90yJqXDG7kEmSywPRdMkDAVdMaJYxr-gN1rC9sX8zAoRRAQDmoBz89z3b351YTJBkR3Mpz6CmN45Vm2dtqAb-0WuMiSbqpfVpkLL2FBumo1lThH9Nq6NqxtUVkpgmtv54PROQcETigvA2fNvBDEG_asLstMzXBjqXDtaU2_LYkdwazhYGt0nk4k2LdsB-miC7FY5gqHDutqydljRVu0ywxFsRBDwuWArojolHMStemO8EWn9LB2iu_kDtjPUlw94ifTlZGA7kBdKQv-0JDVNksxDwIR1JpLYAGc_5rmjETEejaxm07kUm8YrbWbwkm02L4rNpjeYsgkfDh8_uhx_47GL8dezquL11hqilEiQZG3ct_bjLPiwZImt3QjMHdaMJge1Q7mCq6ayIzD3PTkja-v4XAiy7jxmSRyYpjXQtVRDeZsxvqv4kmAXv9PXT2rrWLoZ6Pc_dv4jV7ihRGeAkmgJiqVUqzAe4cNF4ZYXKRUaC7uqbxBofNFpXoHME6Z6W6_EIkZTncFgZ64dkzJOm14A0RYrl3CE9IhNtS2xRsgTLnNc2TBPiFKUt-cJLpM0J4jE5jwBDDCLcAfpY-b6Oq2y0kbtUOpnCvrmqoM9LTWrtm-NfkCSLHrXjr9GZ5eNnj9ZJHqNEv-zarjdExJRh_i6by0VB9Ya2A5R23_71zTELAcriWOME9ZoYXbvnEE0HOgnrqEZXFhtnOsjHpr-qUzsbBEjYl8TE6BeFRQFt5bogXTLMYvCnLqC9S4m9jwdh-R_av70uinjDFfL9Fqb-J_d1J38XOO6rHbjx8hyveias-O19DbHvfFYp2HWfrBtv2T2vekPJfPwCxqtqg450crvPmr0xtXfNcci3Z3n-eTPQs0vv_379PIpKfs_j3uP4asebs0L4ouVn5bB-OnoZnQ9rut-bUX_Mpt1Pp2OvLE38kazmaU_PNjzXw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 44 bytes

```
L=[0...3]
f(l)=join((L[l>0],1),(3-L[l=0],0))
```

I have no idea what this question is asking about; I'm just porting most of the other answers here.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4ojzplhamn)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yvcbqz6yus)

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$16\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 13.17 bytes

```
J/Pj/ JJf142$xe!
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJKL1BqLyBKSmYxNDIkeGUhIiwiWzAsMCwxLDBdIl0=)

Outputs as a PBM image. Port of Jelly, so go upvote that (and the posts that inspired it)!

Comment: How is it that the bit count is fractional (13.17*8=105.36 bits)?

Comment: @Jachdich People decided to allow fractional bits, whether they exist or not https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24251/what-is-our-consensus-for-fractional-byte-functions. I disagree but I can't change the rules.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>35</s> 33 bytes

```
{`0:"P1\n4 2\n",*',/$x,"\n",$|~x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pOMLBSCjCMyTNRMIrJU9LRUtfRV6nQUQKxVWrqKmq5uNKiDRUMFAwVDGPBTDAnFioKZYKlFQxiAS1AEuY=)

Took me quite some time, but I finally got it. Output PBM image data, as that seems to be what everyone's doing.

Forgive me if the explanation doesn't make sense. Neither do I understand it well.

Explanation:

```
{`0:"P1\n4 2\n",*',/$x,"\n",$|~x}    Main program. Takes x as input
                               x     x itself
                             |~      Not, then reverse
                            $        Convert each number to string
                       "\n",         Concat with newline
                      ,              Concat with
                    $x               x, with each number converted to string
                  ,/                 Joined everything together
                *'                   Get the first element of each string.
                                     This is to remove the sub-arrays of the negate-then-reverse x
               ,                     Concat the entire result with
    "P1\n4 2\n"                      PBM hardcoded image data. Defined an image of 2x4 pixels
 `0:                                 Print everything to stdout
```