# Calculate the number of trailing zeros in n!

Tags: code-golf

Write a function which takes n as a parameter, and returns the number of trailing zeros in n!.

### Input Constraints

0 <= n <= 10^100

### Output Constraints

Should be return the result in less than 10 seconds.

### Test Input

```
1
213
45678
1234567
78943533
4567894123
121233112233112231233112323123
```

### Test Output

```
0
51
11416
308638
19735878
1141973522
30308278058278057808278080759
```

Shortest code by character count wins.

Comment: I'm not sure if we should have this here, as it's basically the same as https://www.spoj.pl/SHORTEN/problems/FACTZERO

Comment: @Nabb, I had no idea that this question was on SPOJ. I've put a significantly larger limit on the input here though.

Comment: @Dogbert: The limit is larger but the algorithms here are going to be exactly the same as over at SPOJ.

Comment: for shortest code, you should use the code-golf tag

Comment: It's on Euler as well :) (i think)

Comment: @Nabb, Aaah, your top on the leaderboard.

Comment: Should we tag it "euler project" and "spoiler"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Python, 36 Chars

Ripped from my earlier [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/694/last-non-zero-digit-of-n/697#697)

```py
f=lambda n:n//5+(n//5>0and f(n//5)or 0) #Py3k #39 Chars
f=lambda n:n/5+(n/5>0and f(n/5)or 0) #Before 3.0 #36 Chars
```

Comment: But you still need the input and output right?

Comment: @Debanjan, the question states, `write a function...`.

Comment: @sOle:My bad!I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

## Python <s>50</s> 47 Characters

```py
n=input()
x=5
s=0
while n/x:s+=n/x;x*=5
print s
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <strike>52</strike> 43

```rb
n=gets.to_i;a=0;i=1
a+=n/i*=5while i<n
p a
```

Comment: You could use `(a+=n/i;i*=5)while i<n` to save a char.

Comment: And ofcourse, `p a` as a is a number.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 63 bytes

```hsk
f i=length$filter(\x->x`mod`5/=0)[1..i];main=interact$show.f.read
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 26

```
! `f=:3 :'+/<.y%5^(1+i.144x)'`
```

eg

```
   f 121233112233112231233112323123x
     30308278058278057808278080759
   f 4567894123
     1141973522
   f 0
     0
   f 10^100x
     2499999999999999...99999999999999999982
```

in less than a second for all input examples