# Check B-powersmoothness

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem

from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number#Powersmooth_numbers), a number is called B-powersmooth if all prime powers \$p^v\$ that divide the number satisfy \$p^v \leq B\$. B-powersmoothness is important, for example, for Pollard's p-1 factorization algorithm.

### Task

your task is to get two numbers, \$n\$ and \$B\$, and output if \$n\$ is \$B\$-powersmooth.

### Rules

- You may take the input in [any reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9263/which-number-formats-are-acceptable-in-output)
- Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code wins.
- You can output a truthy/false value, or any two different values for true/false.
- You can assume \$ 1 < B, n \$.

### Test cases

```
n, b -> answer
3, 2 -> 0
10, 7 -> 1
123, 40 -> 0
123, 41 -> 1
64, 2 -> 0
64, 32 -> 0
64, 65 -> 1
720, 5 -> 0
720, 15 -> 0
720, 16 -> 1
20, 5 -> 1
```

Comment: Can we assume \$B \ge 1\$?

Comment: @ovs yes, you can assume that

Comment: Brownie points for beating my 5 bytes 05AB1E solution

Comment: Suggested test cases: `720, 15 -> 0` and `720, 16 -> 1`. All of the current test cases passed a buggy version of my 52 byte .NET regex.

Comment: @Deadcode thanks, I'll add those

Comment: Is [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222701/94066) your solution?

Comment: @Makonede I had à@ in the end instead of @P, but it's about the same

Answer (score 9):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>14</s></sup> 13 bytes

```
<[:>./2^/@p:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/baKt7PT0jeL0HQqsYv9r/jdSSFMw5jIHkoYGXCYGINrImMvEEMoASZuZcBlDaTNTCA2izI0MAA)

*-1 byte thanks to @Jonah*

A dyadic function. The right argument is \$n\$, the left argument is \$B\$. Returns 0 if \$n\$ is \$B\$-powersmooth, 1 otherwise.

#### How it works

```
<[:>./2^/@p:]  NB. left arg = B, right arg = n
      2   p:]  NB. Prime factorization of n,
               NB. given as a 2-row matrix of [primes, exponents]
       ^/@     NB. Evaluate all pi^ei for each prime factor
 [:>./         NB. Maximum of all prime powers found above
<              NB. 1 if the above is greater than B, 0 otherwise
```

Comment: Save 1 byte with `<[:>./2^/@p:]`

Comment: Save 1 byte with `OR@:<2^/@p:]`

Answer (score 8):

## Regex (ECMAScript), 61 bytes

```
^(?=(|x*)\1*(?=\1\b)(?!(((x+)x+)(?=\3+,)\3*\4)\2+,)(x*)).*,\5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/LbsIwELznKwKX7CYhxAGCRORy6oELh/bYtJIBJ7h1TOQYSnlc@wH9xP4INS2oSJZndmZ3PX5lG9bMtahNp6nFgutqpd74x0lTxd/dB17eb2uAHb3r@qcXGFM4bH3MiW9pTvIZwrgFANsA7TlrvSDEvOfnfcwTS8F2Y@SH@eDkd3cYmdWj0UKVgFEjxZxDGnb6iFmx0lBQkoGkmrOFFIoDYouqtZRZQWPciwJaBdZ22ABmji2hpDJqaikMeKFnn5FclWbZosnhIJopmwKjNdMNn9iR8il@Rrwas1uDWAP39do0RkN7ojZMioUrlFVGbcwuhsRsvlJGqDXPjk5Fwdt6keY1ZwYYBjZBcKPMbJyKmfkStA37v@LCPPf788v1AqjGZBTb/x9PvdBNHBKH7tAhiS368QWJk/bP3vnu/UE6cIaJbb0AuWLq/Ko/)

Takes \$n\$ and \$B\$ from input in unary as strings of `x`s whose length represents the number, separated by a `,`.

Uses my [prime power regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210162/is-it-almost-prime/219939#219939), and the same expression for cycling through divisors of N from largest to smallest as [used in this problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/164911/is-this-a-consecutive-prime-constant-exponent-number/179412#179412).

```
# Take input as N in unary, followed by a comma, followed by B in unary
^
(?=
    (|x*)\1*(?=\1\b)  # cycle tail through all of the divisors of N, including N,
                      # from largest to smallest;
                      # \1 = the divisor, or zero if the divisor is N itself
    # Assert tail is a prime power
    (?!               # Assert that the following cannot match
        (             # Capture \2 to be the following:
            ((x+)x+)  # Cycle through all values of \4 and \3 such that \3 > \4 > 1
            (?=\3+,)  # such that \3 is a proper divisor of N
            \3*\4     # Cycle through all values of \2 > \3 that aren't divisible
                      # by \3, by letting \2 = \3 * A + \4 where A >= 0
        )
        \2+,          # where \2 is a proper divisor of N
    )
    (x*)              # \5 = the largest prime power factor of N
)
.*,                   # tail = B
\5                    # Assert that \5 <= B
```

## Regex (ECMAScript), <s>61</s> 59 bytes

Adapting [Neil's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/222668/2) of taking the arguments in \$(B,n)\$ order saves 2 bytes:

```
^(x*),(?!(x*)\2*(?=\2\b)(?!(((x+)x+)(?=\4+$)\4*\5)\3+$)x\1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9BbsIwEEX3OUVAlTKThJCEABKRy6oLNizaZdNKBpzg1pjIMTSFsu0BesReJHVaUJEsv5n/Z6zvF7qn1VLxUveqkq@Y2mzlK3tvFJHszb5nxV1dAhzIbd9tnqF20Ydpp2UWuzAlWZwtsFUAag/NabXEu8EscbMhZgNT1lmEjds/YKC3D1pxWQAGleBLBiO/lyCm@VZBTqIUBFGMrgSXDBA7RO6ESHMS4pHn0MmxNMsaMLVMCwURQVUKrsHxHcRAMFnodYfEHx@8mtM5UFJSVbGZWSkewyfEi7G4NiJj4LHc6Uor6M7kngq@srk0yqSL6dkQmC63UnO5Y@nJ2hBwaidQrGRUwwI9k8C7UqiJs6F6uQZlwv4/ca4c@/vzy3Y82EyjSWj@f2oGvh1bUejbYyuKTZOEZ0bWKGm99h78YTS0xrEZPSO6cGT9qj8)
<sup>(For convenience, this test harness takes the arguments in \$(n,B)\$ order and passes them to the regex in reverse order.)</sup>

```
# Take input as B in unary, followed by a comma, followed by N in unary
^
(x*),                 # \1 = B; tail = N
(?!                   # Assert that the following cannot match
    (x*)\2*(?=\2\b)   # cycle tail through all of the divisors of N, including N;
                      # \2 = the divisor, or zero if the divisor is N itself
    # Assert tail is a prime power
    (?!               # Assert that the following cannot match
        (             # Capture \3 to be the following:
            ((x+)x+)  # Cycle through all values of \5 and \4 such that \4 > \5 > 1
            (?=\4+$)  # such that \4 is a proper divisor of N
            \4*\5     # Cycle through all values of \3 > \4 that aren't divisible
                      # by \4, by letting \3 = \4 * A + \5 where A >= 0
        )
        \3+$          # where \3 is a proper divisor of N
    )
    x\1               # Assert tail > B
)
```

## Regex (ECMAScript 2018 / .NET), <s>54</s> 52 bytes

*-2 bytes by using [Neil's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/222668/2) but with the arguments in \$(n,B)\$ order*

```
$(?<!^\4*(?!(((x+)x+)(?=\2+,)\2*\3)\1+,)(x+\5),(x+))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBNTsMwEIX3OUVaIXmmCVacllZqMFmx6IYFLAmoJnVTI@ME2/2RgC0H4IhcpLgFpErWvPF8b6wZP4uNcLVVnT837ULuHc8Ky29lc73r4M5bZRpqxXa@P4PysvdYjQZQ9gBgl2A4UPIqT1Ks8kE1xIqFNJDqAtODAfdz6rSqJbD0nCEWVr6ulZVArBQLrYwkSOuQezkzXtqlCNY3Zbq1n3a2raVz1PmFMh9IWwPk2JFqfvXWcE1dp5UHkhIs1BLA8IZqaRq/wh7P39@VuxE3IHgnrDs8D8199oD4D55OAQsA/cq22/7MbIRWi9gK08hp3E90EZ3M0q493VrlJYArSWXIlBBMdELi78@vmCQAZEeolV1YCgQmYbzkpPKESF@Er1dgsWTTLPyJ46z4wP0wjfOIZWk8iVgeLqPsT1k0Hh3YIQ5/ZXwRTfJg/RP2r@PoWP0B) - ECMAScript 2018
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDRatswFH33V8hhEClRjOWkKVTTMgh7KLRsLIU91B0ojpwIFNmV5MzFzes@YJ@4D5kn2@leJoSOrs659x7dzM6ywohW86OwJc8E2LxYJ45NZaXegzVbF9oWStAhfhC1i76KfaW4@VSXRlgrvYBmilsLjo113MkMnAq5A/dcagBRc@IGWPZx1L6Dq/fh93QxgasQQlhPkd9wxdJkilGaTNI5Som/eia9QrgToHZEu3zDtPgBfGNRQxttqq11xvuBBNvoTui9O8wShHv@c@k6S9G6OJZSiR2igxYomhcGSu2AZjGFiq39T/juTmoBEQqZrpSimhHUyBzqDzFaR9@MdGIQ9DZKpqJNqaSDYzxGtKvF8ZYGPqG8@AhZ8voaeiZ6MC9fuLEClo/xEy4qr0X/U2SgtuitHRzd6hNXfoCG6724AU18HmGFqFBW9MOs@2FshgmM6zHm0@2UIFppy3PR5LIWO5gduJk8sxo1z4/8iXm/9Hz@18LXBL9//gIN6WpjE93ae@6yA6zRitzEyGv9aucYJAGJMbgOSOKDRXxBEiwXHded8wGWV8F14qUXIG@4DPrXP1mu@N62s8HlXw) - .NET

This works by first capturing \$B\$, then asserting that there does not exist any \$a>B\$ for which \$a\$ is a prime power that divides \$N\$.

```
# Take input as N in unary, followed by a comma, followed by B in unary
$                     # head = B
(?<!                  # Negative lookbehind; assert that it's not possible to find a
                      # match for the following. Evaluated from right-to-left, so read
                      # the inside of this from bottom to top (but go back to top-down
                      # order for reading inside the negative lookbehind)
    ^\4*              # Assert that \4 divides N
    # Assert tail is a prime power
    (?!               # Negative lookahead; assert that the following cannot match
        (             # Capture \1 to be the following:
            ((x+)x+)  # Cycle through all values of \3 and \2 such that \2 > \3 > 1
            (?=\2+,)  # such that \2 is a proper divisor of N
            \2*\3     # Cycle through all values of \1 > \2 that aren't divisible
                      # by \2, by letting \1 = \2 * A + \3 where A >= 0
        )
        \1+,          # where \2 is a proper divisor of N
    )    
    (x+\5)            # \4 = tail = any divisor of N greater than B; the "^\5*" above
                      #      asserts it to be a divisor of N. Note that in most regex
                      #      engines, putting the "^\5*" later than the negative
                      #      assertion, as is the case here, results in a slowdown, as
                      #      non-divisors of N will be tested for being prime powers.
    ,(x+)             # \5 = head = B
)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
&YF^<a
```

Inputs `n` then `B`.

Outputs `0` if *n* is *B*-powersmooth or `1` otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Xy3SLc4m8f9/QyNjLhMDAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8F8t0i3OJvG/S8h/Yy4jLkMDLnMuQyNjLhMDCGXIZWYCFAcSxmDSzJTL3MiAyxQA)

#### How it works

```
&YF  % Implicit input: n. Factorization with primes and exponents as separate outputs
^    % Element-wise power
<    % Implicit input: B. Less-than comparison, element-wise
a    % Any: gives true (1) if any value is nonzero, or false (0) otherwise
     % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
ḋḅ∋×>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuaHWzsedSxXKikqTdVTqgEx0xJzioHs2oe7Omsfbp3w/@GO7oc7Wh91dB@ebvf/f3S0sY5RrE60oYGOOYgyMtYxMYAxDIEMMxOwPJAyhtJmpkDa3MhAxzQ2FgA)

Takes \$n\$ through the input variable and \$B\$ through the output variable; fails if \$n\$ is \$B\$-powersmooth and succeeds if not.

```
 ḅ       Take the runs of consecutive equal elements from
ḋ        the prime factors of n.
  ∋      For some run,
   ×     the product of its elements
    >    is greater than B.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes.factors`, 37 bytes

```
[ group-factors unzip v^ supremum < ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/NCsIwEITvPsW8gKFN/0DFq3jxIp5EIZRUPaSN2aSgpc8eY0p72f12dwZmG1HbzvjL@Xg6bCCIupqghH3GwrR5KUmsiarpwHo5DdpIaz9B0VqQfDvZ1pKwXQ0YwJFhDL1CmkTIE6R82uXpghxlHiFbqCxmKlDxv3n0VzxM5/R6juHa70ujv4NcCKGcwg43PwRtfGCvhAbzPw)

### Explanation:

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes `B` and `n` (in that order) as input and returns a (flipped) boolean as output.

- `group-factors` obtain the prime factorization of `n` as a sequence of pairs
- `unzip` get the factors in one sequence and the exponents in another
- `v^` element-wise exponentiation of two vectors
- `supremum` find the maximum value
- `<` is `B` less than this value?

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
≤⁰▲mΠgp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fe2j5o6bGR20THrVN@v@oc8mjxg2Ppm3KPbcgveD////R0UY6xrE60eY6hgZAysRAx9AIxDcxhDKMdMxMgJQxlDYzhdCmOuZGBrGxAA)

```
      p        # get the list of prime factors of arg2;
     g         # group equal ones together
   mΠ          # and multiply them together (to get the prime power divisors);
  ▲            # get the maximum of these;
≤⁰             # is it ≤ arg1?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ÆF*/€Ṁ>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm5uW/qOmNQ93Ntj9///f0OC/OQA)

Similar to Bubbler's answer. Returns a flipped boolean.

### Explanation

```
ÆF*/€Ṁ< Main link: takes  n on the left, and B on the right
ÆF      prime factor and exponent pairs
  */€   reduce each by exponentiation
     Ṁ  maximum
      > greater than B?
```

Comment: `<` should be an equivalent of `≤` instead (or `>` to get a flipped boolean).

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

The output is a positive integer for truthy cases and a `0` otherwise.

```python
f=lambda n,b,p=2,m=1:b/m*(n<2or f(*[n/p,n,b,b,p,p+1,m*p][n%p>0::2]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3NCoMwEITvPsUgBBK7RY1/INUXEQ@KlQoaQ8ylT28TKS0sy7ezszv6bV@7kuc5N@uwjdMARSPpRtLWpPUYbxFXD7kbzDzqVKzJr52B9C2lLdJ9p5huk7qWvRCnfR72QAOeEaQg8DQhVBdIJ@XJH1OPZf71ech@VBaeKumOCxEEs4tXhBGLwpVQB4BxMTP3snCTNouyCNlEYBPure@cTSIEw2Vyte8rN@6xEecH)

**Commented:**

```python
f=lambda n,b,p=2,m=1:         # recursive function taking 4 arguments
                              # n, b - inputs from the challenge
                              # p=2  - candidate for a prime dividing n
                              # m=1  - a power of p dividing the original input n
b/m*( ... )                   # floor division, this is 0 if m>b
     n<2or ...                # if n==1, return True (1), else:
           f(*[ ... ][1::2])  # if n%p>0 (p does not divide n):
        == f(n,b,p+1)         #   try next p
           f(*[ ... ][0::2])  # if n%p==0 (p divides n):
        == f(n/p,b,p,m*p)     #   divide n by p, update power of p, m
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>108</s> 107 bytes

```hs
1!_=[]
n!f|n`mod`f<1=f:(n`div`f)!f|x<-f+1=n!x
g(h:t)x|h`mod`x<1=h*x:t|1>0=x:h:t
n#b=all(<=b)$foldl g[1]$n!2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3BjoIwFEX3fMUDXbTTklBUTAjlC8aVS0IEgrVmSjHIzHTBv2PFTZ1ZnvPObWV9/zorNc/MP/Gi9LQvJl11fVuJjHGRIl21159KYOtNFgrCuPaNd0EyHbGZ5JIam8oPk44TyyNuUnvz9KrhtVIo4w1ei161Ci4FK9faj@euvmre1bfDCW7f43EcPjUUd9n/Ik0bTEgAPIeAEHi5VYPBwjA9z3TAWVigDYWYBhDmEAWYIhZR2L@YLRzbYBu5xWKY0yTb9zeevPkrkp2z2Mf2m51TLIL9N4kzcjaWy3J@AA)

- saved 1 thanks to @Unrelated String
- `!` finds all prime factors : it divides n by 2 while modulo is 0 then by 3, then by 4.. Wait 4 is not prime! Ah but it was already factorized by 2
- `g` all that to group factors
- `#` finally we return True if all are <= B

Comment: [-1 by making `?` not infix](https://tio.run/##ZY3BjoIwFEX3fMUDXbTTklBUTAjlC8aVS0IEgrVmSjHIzHTBv2PFTZ1ZnvPObWV9/zorNc/MP/Gi9LQvJl11fVuJjHGRIl21159KYOtNFgrCuPaNd0EyHbGZ5JIam8oPk44TyyNuUnvz9KrhtVIo4w1ei161Ci4FK9faj@euvmre1bfDCW7f43EcPjUUd9n/Ik0bTEgAPIeAEHi5VYPBwjA9z3TAWVigDYWYBhDmEAWYIhZR2L@YLRzbYBu5xWKY0yTb9zeevPkrkp2z2Mf2m51TLIL9N4kzcjaWy3J@AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>63</s> <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```
.+
$*
Mr`^\4*(?!(((1+)1+)(?=\2+¶)\2*\3)\1+¶)(1+\5)¶(1+)$
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZyg819Pm0tFi8u3KCEuxkRLw15RQ0PDUFsTiDTsbWOMtA9t04wx0oox1owxBLGBcjGmmoe2gdSocBn8/2@sY8RlaKBjzmVoZKxjYgChDLnMTIDiQMIYTJqZcpkbGeiYAgA) Takes line-separated input `n,B` but test suite converts from comma-separated for convenience. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to a hint by @Deadcode. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert `n` and `B` to unary.

```
Mr`^\4*(?!(((1+)1+)(?=\2+¶)\2*\3)\1+¶)(1+\5)¶(1+)$
```

Try to find (in `$4`) an integer that is greater than `b`, a power of a prime, and a factor of `n`. The `r` flag makes the expression match from the right, so `$5` is matched to `b` first, then `$4`, then `$4` is checked for the power of a prime (taken from @Deadcode's answer to [Is it almost-prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210162), matching left-to-right as it is a lookahead), then it is checked for a factor of `n`. The previous 63-byte version was faster because it checked for factors before prime powers:  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZygw@WvEpegp831H4hVtLh8E@I0DLU1D20DkjGGmhr2tjFGWipA2kbx0LYYY22NGNMYEy0g1xbINdHWBCoDqQcCLoP//411jLgMDXTMuQyNjHVMDCCUIZeZCVAcSBiDSTNTLnMjAx1TAA)

```
0
```

Check that there wasn't a match.

Comment: It's also 63 bytes with the arguments in non-reversed order and no need to logical-not the truthiness of the regex: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZygw@WvwvVfT5tLRYsrTsPeVsNQWzPGUOvQNg17G1sNe0UNDZAIEAHlYoy1D23TjDHWijHRjDECsw2BhKYeUHmM4f//xjpGXIYGOuZchkbGOiYGEMqQy8wEKA4kjMGkmSmXuZGBjikA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online") (this is just my ECMAScript 2018 regex)

Comment: 60 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZygw@WvwvVfT5tLRYsrTsPeTsNQWzPGUOvQNg17G1sNe0UNDZAIEGnY28YYax/aphljrBVjohljBGYbAgkg@f@/sY4Rl6GBjjmXoZGxjokBhDLkMjMBigMJYzBpZsplbmSgYwoA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Deadcode I found a better golf... slow though!

Comment: Oh, nicely done! Why do I always forget to do that `(?=A)(?!B)` → `(?!B)A` golf. At this point it's really rather ridiculous how many times I've forgotten to do it!

Comment: 58 bytes by taking the arguments in regular order (\$n,B)\$: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZygw@WvwvVfT5tLRYtLRcPeRjEuxlRLw15RQ0PDUFsTiDTsbWOMtA9t04wx0oox1owxBLGBcjGmmoe2gdRo/v9vrGPEZWigY85laGSsY2IAoQy5zEyA4kDCGEyamXKZGxnomAIA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Deadcode You know what? I had previously investigated reversing my original 63-byte version, but because it costs a byte to reverse the match direction with the `r` flag, and I had a lookahead which would have turned into a lookbehind, it would still have been 63 bytes. But of course I've now eliminated the lookahead... I think your `^\5*` needs to be `^\4*` though.

Comment: Thanks... I didn't notice the bug because all of the current test cases passed.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>53</s>  52 bytes

Expects `(b)(n)`. Returns **0** or **true**.

```javascript
b=>g=(n,i=d=1)=>i>b?0:n%++d?d>n||g(n,1):g(n/d,i*d--)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc5LDoIwEIDhvafoxqQj1D6okJC0nAUokBrSGjGuuHtt1AWpj9Usvvwzc27v7dJf7eVGnDdDGFXolJ4UdrlVRnFQ2uquYbXbZ5lpjHbrOkXkUMdBTW4PhhAIvXeLn4fj7Cc8YiQAI1QAIEoR2yVYReTshTxByQBz8aOUfINp@bxZyu9l8Q/L0wY/1kasxPtbFh4)

#### Commented

```javascript
b =>          // outer function taking b = powersmoothness rank
g = (         // recursive inner function taking:
  n,          //   n = input integer whose b-powersmoothness is tested
  i =         //   i = exponentiation of the current prime divisor,
              //       which must never exceed b
  d = 1       //   d = prime divisor candidate
) =>          //
i > b ?       // if i is greater than b:
  0           //   failure: stop and return 0
:             // else:
  n % ++d ?   //   increment d; if it's not a divisor of n:
    d > n     //     stop and return true if it's greater than n
    ||        //     otherwise:
      g(      //       do a recursive call:
        n,    //         pass n unchanged
        1     //         reset i to 1 while leaving d unchanged
      )       //       end of recursive call
  :           //   else (d is a prime divisor of n):
    g(        //     do a recursive call:
      n / d,  //       divide n by d
      i * d-- //       multiply i by d, decrement d afterwards
    )         //     end of recursive call
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

*Ties [Unrelated String's Brachylog answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222678/94066) for #1.*

```
ÒγP@P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8KRzmwMcAv7/NzQy5jIxBAA)

```
ÒγP@P  # full program
    P  # product of...
       # (implicit) list of...
   @   # whether...
       # implicit input...
   @   # is greater than or equal to...
  P    # products of...
 γ     # consecutive runs of...
Ò      # prime factors of...
       # implicit input
       # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>66</s> 64 bytes

```c
t;r;p;f(n,B){for(r=p=1;n/++p;r&=t/n<=B)for(t=n;n%p<1;n/=p);t=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHtaoMwFP3fp7gIDq0p9aPtGGn2o2NPsZZRNXayLQ1JYLLiq8/dtNHZMvEcbnLOuSbXYnYoiq4zVFFJq0CQTXiqjipQTLKEinkUSarumJmLNduEVjFMUOHLtVWZDKlhirbd574WQTg5TQCfWhgwXJtX8bLDJYNTRiCJEWnmaLX4w30ajymNW3rdJu/bpGghsEDTIkEjgQyxWhLAN7FYYTlK80bywvAS85i2ByAw8E2RuFzxtldTZF68c3UJetvmOd02D0@IpUdgvM48l8PZQGA/WouSNxiLqSvXoOtvfqyC/jjh3G1Mhx0KUXR2h3CZYX8FgZ3cLM/6jl7JeS/n/8oaZftXIQ@vBY7CMJ3bpFRoqQLPLwn4JcweLft6K/DuthcBTYYJacb4znVvJ233U1Qf@4PuZl@/)

Takes two integers \$n\$ and \$B\$ as input and returns \$1\$ if \$n\$ is \$B\$-powersmooth or \$0\$ otherwise.

#### Explanation

```c
t;r;p;f(n,B){                           // function taking two int inputs
                                        // n and B
             for(r=p=1;                 // loop over prime factors p of n
                                        // also init return value r to 1
                       n/++p;           // loop while p<=n also bump p
                             r&=t/n<=B) // at the end of each loop check that
                                        // the current prime power factor of
                                        // n (t/n) is less than or equal to B
                  for(                  // loop to strip n of all its
                                        // prime factors p
                      t=n;              // save copy of n in t before 
                                        // removing all p factors
                          n%p<1;        // loop while p is a factor of n
                                n/=p);  // reduce n by p  
             t=r;                       // return r  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
FkrPE8 aY^@k1@k0;<eSYhE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3y27KMDVQiExMs4h29Ah28DaJjU4MsP1/39DIwMucwA)

## Explanation

```
Fk    For loop with the iterator as k
E     Take first input.
PE    List of prime factors
rPE8  Run length encoding over the list, eg: [2, 2, 3] becomes [[2, 2], [1, 3]]
Y     Initialized to an empty list by default.
@k1   Element at index 1 of k.
@k0   Element at index 0 of k.
^     Apply exponentiation.
aY    Append element to Y
SY    Sort Y
e     Last element
hE    Take next input and increment by 1
<     Is it less than?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 48 bytes

```ruby
->n,b{(2..n).none?{|x|n/(n/=x while n%x<1;n)>b}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PJ6law0hPL09TLy8/L9W@uqaiJk9fI0/ftkKhPCMzJ1UhT7XCxtA6T9Muqbb2f3S0sY5RrE60oYGOOYgyMtYxMYAxDIEMMxOwPJAyhtJmpkDa3MhAR8E0NlYvN7GgugZoaU2BQjSQ0kkDkbGxtf8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 76 bytes

```javascript
n=>g=b=>{for(++b,p=1;b%++p;);for(q=b;q%p<1;q/=p);return n%b|q>1&&b<n&&g(b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NjoMgFIX3PgUbLQSqYv8WFHbzFNNJKhatjQVEaprM9NkdHCeT2X33nC83ObdyLIfKtdavtbmoqeaT5qLhkovP2jiIsSSWUyZjjC1DbM56Llkf2yNlfcYtYk75h9NAx/KrFzRJ5FEnSQMlYq/JAw7O0YaAAqwFyCOaE3CYkUa0CPE2/81/Dro0@@2fP@PmH@93i3IowqPdkp9T79o7ROlgu9bD1UmvUHovLXwCLsAzoK@uMDtdcNYsxTgXeESIRT4Nk97KIMB3TSRRHyhMjyqjB9OptDMNrKFGYQ0BKvgvxKZv)

Return `false` if n is B-powersmooth. Return `0` otherwise. (as per two different values rule)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 37 bytes

```
ＮθＷ¬⁼θΠυ⊞υ§Φ…·²θ¬﹪÷θ∨Πυ¹κ⁰¬›⌈ＥυＸι№υιＮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU@7DsIwDNz5ioyOFCRAQgydEC91ACr@ILQRtUgTmsaFvw9OF/Bwlk5353Pd6lB7bVMq3Yvihbq7CdDLYvZu0RoBFx/h0JO2A/RKVME3VEcgySMqGlogJbaxdI35wBFtZHfpaksDjuam3cPASoleKpGDzuy2ngVxjyM2JkdeA/xSlVhKhqfMuJBcowro4tTiFIzO8Wf9wY463q98vPJvJlGJnSdWMoNysv8/lJkipc1qMVun@Wi/) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for smooth, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
ＮθＷ¬⁼θΠυ⊞υ§Φ…·²θ¬﹪÷θ∨Πυ¹κ⁰
```

Input `n` and find its prime factors (taken from my answer to [Zeroes at end of \$n!\$ in base \$m\$](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220840)).

```
¬›⌈ＥυＸι№υιＮ
```

Raise each prime factor to its multiplicity and compare the largest to `B`.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 149 bytes

```
=LET(q,SEQUENCE(A2),f,(MOD(A2,q)=0)*q,o,(MMULT(1*(MOD(f,TRANSPOSE(q))=0),q^0)=2)*f,p,FILTER(o,o),MAX((MMULT(1*(MOD(f,TRANSPOSE(p))=0),p^0)=1)*f)<=B2)
```

Explanation

```
=LET(                                        'function that allows variable assignment,
                                                 returns the value of the last parameter
q,SEQUENCE(A2)                               'q = list of numbers from 1 to n
f,(MOD(A2,q)=0)*q                            'f = if n mod q = 0 then q else 0
o,(MMULT(1*(MOD(f,TRANSPOSE(q))=0),q^0)=2)*f 'o = if f is prime then f else 0
         1*(MOD(f,TRANSPOSE(q))=0)           'matrix of f by q where 1 indicates f mod q = 0
                                   q^0       'vertical matrix of q 1's
   MMULT(                             )      'need to use matrix multiplication to sum  
                                                 each row inside a LET
                                       =2)*f 'if sum of the row is 2 (prime) then f else 0
p,FILTER(o,o)                                'p = all o where o <> 0
        1*(MOD(f,TRANSPOSE(p))=0)            'matrix of f by p where 1 indicates f mod p = 0
MAX((MMULT(                   ,p^0)=1*f)<=b2 'TRUE if largest f with one prime factor <= b
```

[Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnA0cp0ESrUoybng-?e=WSAPim)

Answer (score 1):

## [Orst](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Orst-Geo), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Orst-Geo/wiki/Code-Page)

```
κñˋςᏓ{ᏓĖΐÇ}Ñδ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy8qLvn//9yuwxtPd59vetg/uRqIj0w7N@Fwe@3hiee2/P//3/y/geG//IKSzPy84v@6OQA)

As hex bytes, this is

```
DE 87 FF D0 E7 FF 47 FF A0 FF 47 18 DD 0E FF A5 2F D4
```

Encoding as UTF-8:

```
Þ‡ÿÐçÿGÿ ÿGÝÿ¥/Ô
```

### How it works

```
κñˋςᏓ{ᏓĖΐÇ}Ñδ - Full program. Takes b, then a
κ             - Save b in variable $x
 ñˋ           - Remove and swap. Stack is [a]
   ςᏓ         - Base-and-powers; Prime decomposition of a
     {    }Ñ  - Over each pair:
      ᏓĖ      -   Reduce by power
        ΐ     -   Retrieve b
         Ç    -   Less than or equal?
            δ - True for all?
```