# Mathematical Combination

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

Write a program that takes an input such as:

```
n,k
```

which then computes:

$$\binom n k = \frac {n!} {k!(n-k)!}$$

and then prints the result.

---

A numerical example:

Input:

```
5,2
```

Internal computation:

$$\frac {5!} {3!\times2!}$$

Printed Output:

```
10
```

---

I'd like to see an answer that beats my python solution of 65 characters, but all languages are obviously welcome.

Here's my solution:

```
n,k=input();f=lambda x:+(x<2)or x*f(x-1);print f(n)/(f(k)*f(n-k))
```

**Edit:**

I admit that this question is from the [codegolf website](http://codegolf.com/choose) mathematical combination puzzle.  I know that my answer may look like not much progress can be made on it, but the leaders of this puzzle have solved it in nearly half as many characters.

Comment: Function or full program? Your description says function that returns the correct result, but your example is a full program that prints it.

Comment: @Ventero You're right I meant program.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Generally, basic math concepts aren't great golf questions because J, APL, Maple, Mathematica and many others will have them built in.  Also, be a bit more specific about input and output format, and provide example results - I can't tell if you mean 5 choose 2 or 2 choose 5 here.

Comment: @Jesse I got this challenge from another website that only allows major scripting languages, I'll remember this guideline in the future.  I edited my question to try and make the challenge requirements more clear, let me know if its clear enough or not.

Comment: I'm new, so we're in much the same boat. However, don't summarize the results; they will just get outdated. Just vote and (if appropriate) accept answers. (Also, you'll make people unhappy if you ignore J and GolfScript answers without a reason.)

Comment: @Jesse those aren't the answers from this page, they're the records from the other website and (as far as I know) the lowest possible counts.

Comment: @Jesse: Whether it's 5C2 or 2C5 is pretty easy to figure out, though, as you wouldn't normally want the latter ;-)

Comment: What about additional output to stderr, will that be ignored?

Comment: Even this will work:`n,k=input();f=lambda x:x<2or x*f(x-1);print f(n)/(f(k)*f(n-k))`

Answer (score 12):

### C 96

With I/O (which takes about 34 chars). Added a couple of newlines to make it readable.

```
main(a,b,c,d){scanf("%d,%d",&a,&b);
d=a-b;for(c=1;a>b;){c*=a--;}for(;d;)
{c/=d--;}printf("%d",c);}
```

Now if you'll excuse me, I have an ASCII n choose k rocket to catch.

```
    d;main(a
   ,         b
  ,           c
 )  int        a
 ;   {scanf    (
 (   "%d %d"   )
 ,   &a,  &b   )
 ;   d    =a   -
 b   +     b   -
 b   *     1   ;
 a             -
 a  ;for    (  c
 =  1;a>   b   ;
 )  {c=   c    *
 (  (a-- )     )
 ;  }for(      b
 =  b + 1      ;
 d  ;    )     {
 c  =     c    /
 (  d--    )   ;
  }           {
  }           {
   }         (
  printf("%d",c)
 )      ;       }
/*     *  *   * *\
 * * X   * 8 * * |
|     *      *    \
*/    //       *  */
```

Answer (score 11):

## APL, 3 bytes

```
⎕!⎕
```

Or for those whose browser doesn't render the above, in an ASCII rendering:

```
{Quad}!{Quad}
```

Comment: To be completely conformant to the `n,k` input, you'd have to do `!/⌽⎕`.

Answer (score 9):

## R (11 Chars)

```
choose(n,r)
```

Comment: You can save 5 bytes (and make it compliant with modern I/O rules) by removing `(n,r)`

Answer (score 7):

### GolfScript, 17 chars

This solution handles cases like k=0 or k=1 correctly.

```
~>.,,]{1\{)*}/}//
```

Factorial-like portion is based off [a previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/607/find-the-factorial/629#629).

Answer (score 6):

### Ruby 1.9, <del>52</del>  46 (42) characters

```
eval"A,B="+gets;i=0;p eval"(A-B+i+=1)/i*"*B+?1
```

If stderr is ignored:

```
eval"A,B=I="+gets;p eval"I/(A-I-=1)*"*B+?1
```

Ruby 1.8, 43 characters, no additional output to stderr:

```
eval"a,b=i="+gets;p eval"i/(a-i-=1)*"*b+"1"
```

Edits:

- (52 -> 48) Found a shorter way to parse the input
- (48 -> 46) Less looping, more eval.

Answer (score 6):

## GolfScript 21

```
~~)>.,,]{{)}%{*}*}%~/
```

Not particularly short, GolfScript lacks a real factorial function, however this has got to be the most wicked data manipulation that I have ever done, this calls for a stack trace:

"5,2" Data on the stack from input.
`~` Eval command, note that , is an operator that turns a number into an array.
[0 1 2 3 4] 2
`~` Binary not.
[0 1 2 3 4] -3
`)` Increment.
[0 1 2 3 4] -2
`>` Take end of array, -2 as parameter to get the last 2 elements.
[3 4]
`.` Duplicate element.
[3 4] [3 4]
`,` Array length.
[3 4] 2
`,` Turn number to array.
[3 4] [0 1]
`]` Create array.
[[3 4] [0 1]]
`{{)}%{*}*}` Block of code.
[[3 4] [0 1]] {{)}%{*}*}
`%` Execute block once for each element of the array. The following part only demonstrate the first loop.
[3 4]
`{)}%` Increment each array element.
[4 5]
`{*}` Block containing a multiply command.
[4 5] {*}
`*` "Fold" the array using the block command, that is in this case make the product of all elements.
20
After the big loop has finished it returns an array with the results.
[20 2]
`~` Deconstruct the array.
20 2
`/` Division.
10

Answer (score 4):

### Python (56)

```
f=lambda n,k:k<1and 1or f(n-1,k-1)*n/k;print f(*input())
```

Ungolfed code and some explanation of a shortcut for calculating the binomial coefficient.  (Note: There is some insight that I just haven't figured out in order to get down to the 39 char version; I don't think this approach will get you there.)

```
# Since choose(n,k) =
#
#     n!/((n-k)!k!)
#
#          [n(n-1)...(n-k+1)][(n-k)...(1)]
#        = -------------------------------
#            [(n-k)...(1)][k(k-1)...(1)]
#
# We can cancel the terms:
#
#     [(n-k)...(1)]
#
# as they appear both on top and bottom, leaving:
#
#    n (n-1)     (n-k+1)
#    - ----- ... -------
#    k (k-1)       (1)
#
# which we might write as:
#
#      choose(n,k) = 1,                      if k = 0
#                  = (n/k)*choose(n-1, k-1), otherwise
#
def choose(n,k):
    if k < 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return choose(n-1, k-1) * n/k

# input() evaluates the string it reads from stdin, so "5,2" becomes
# (5,2) with no further action required on our part.
#
# In the golfed version, we make use of the `*` unpacking operator, 
# to unpack the tuple returned by input() directly into the arguments
# of f(), without the need for intermediate variables n, k at all.
#
n, k = input()

# This line is left as an exercise to the reader.
print choose(n, k)
```

Comment: Could you provide an ungolfed example of your script?

Comment: Can we use `*` for parsing inputs of the form `4545 78`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, but it's not `*` that's the issue. `4545 78` isn't a valid Python expression, so `input()` will raise a `SyntaxError`.  This trick depends entirely on the problem asking for `x,y`.  If you had a function that read `x y` and returned a tuple, then you could use `*` with that just fine.

Answer (score 4):

### RPL (4)

(using built-in function)

```
COMB
```

Answer (score 3):

### Windows PowerShell, 57

```
$a,$b=iex $input
$p=1
for($a-=$b;$a-ge1){$p*=1+$b/$a--}$p
```

Answer (score 3):

## J, <strike>33</strike> 36

```
(":!~/".;._1}:toJ',',1!:1(3))1!:2(4)
```

35 characters are input, parsing and output. The other character, `!`, is n choose k.

I don't have Windows around for testing this at the moment, but I believe it should work there.

Answer (score 3):

## Q, 32 chars

```
{f:{1*/1.+(!)x};f[x]%f[y]*f x-y}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
n,k=input()
B=2<<n
print(B+1)**n/B**k%B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/pfnpGZk6pgaJVakZqspKT0P08n2zYzr6C0REOTy8nWyMYmj6ugKDOvRMNJ21BTSytP30lLK1vV6T9IraGBjiEXkDDiMtAx4DLVMQYA)

A full program, as the challenge asks for. The method is explained in [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169115/20260).

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 6 (55)

```
my ($a,$b)=lines;$_=1;for 1..$a-$b {$_+=$_*$b/$^a};.say
```

Answer (score 2):

### RPL (22)

(not using built-in COMB function)

```
→ n k 'n!/(k!*(n-k)!)'
```

Answer (score 2):

### Q (<strike>50</strike> 45)

```
 f:{(prd 1.+til x)%((prd 1.+til y)*prd 1.+til x-y)}
```

You can shave a few characters off the above by removing redundant brackets and using 1*/ instead of prd.

```
f:{(1*/1.+til x)%(1*/1.+til y)*1*/1.+til x-y}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 12

Straightforward, built-in function.

```
n~Binomial~k
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>25</s> 16 bytes

*-9 bytes thanks to nwellnhof*

```perl6
+*o&combinations
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX1srXy05PzcpMy@xJDM/r/i/NVdxYqVCmoapjpEmjG1ogMwx1TE00LT@DwA)

Anonymous function that takes two numbers and returns an int. This uses the built-in `combinations` and converts the returned list to an int.

Comment: [16 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX1srXy05PzcpMy@xJDM/r/i/NVdxYqVCmoapjpEmjG1ogMwx1TE00LT@DwA "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Comment: @nwellnhof Ah, I didn't realise `combinations` could take an number instead of a list

Answer (score 1):

### PHP (71 <strike>79</strike>)

```
<?$a=fgetcsv(STDIN);$x=1;while($a[1]-$i)$x=$x*($a[0]-++$i+1)/$i;echo$x;
```

```
<?php $a=fgetcsv(STDIN);$x=1;while(++$i<=$a[1])$x=$x*($a[0]-$i+1)/$i;echo $x?>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python (54)

```
f=lambda n,k:k<1or f(n-1,k-1)*n/k;print 1*f(*input())
```

Essentially the same as the Python one above, but I shave off four bytes by dropping the

```
and 1
```

from the function definition. However, this results in the function returning True instead of 1 if k=0, but this can be fixed by multiplying with 1 before printing, since 1*True=1, thus adding two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### J, 11 characters

```
!~/".1!:1[1
```

Takes input from the keyboard.

```
    !~/".1!:1[1
5,2
10
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 21 bytes

```python
import math
math.comb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRCE3sSSDC0ToJefnJv0vKMrMK9GA8zVMdRSMNDX/AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/5////pv@NAA)

[2 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9Z/////6Y6RgA) to take input as `n,k`

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 53 bytes

```rust
fn f(n:i32,k:i32)->i32{if k<1{1}else{f(n-1,k-1)*n/k}}
```

This is essentially the same as the Python code in some of the previous answers, and computes the binomial coefficient through recursion.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxCoAgEADQub7CnLxQwqKlon9pSBDtCK3puG@3XN700puf4lBch0cFgtrmTh6fiJ2SxFILp2Y9Aqwt1@YULn4adaiC2X/JOxE2S5bPmE/6h7E6GAs9DoG5lA8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 58 bytes

```go
func b(n,k int)int{if k<1{return 1}
return b(n-1,k-1)*n/k}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY47DoMwDIZncgqLiZTQNlvF4w7dOwEiyEkxKAoT4iRdUKUeokfpbRoekl_6bP2_X--2X75DWZuybaArkRh2Q28dhKpz4Wd0Krn9UjVSDVVEwgCS4z4nVGByOdnGjZZAzuyY_FUihUkkP9HFzIfCY1NY9SMOEwtUbwHTQmaYF_KaYRx7uFG9Up0XmOkdBv6R8916zydFKLSo1sq5X83Mx2GxLHv_Aw)

#### Alternative using `math.Gamma()`, 82 bytes

```go
import."math"
func b(n,k float64)float64{g:=Gamma
return g(n+1)/(g(k+1)*g(n-k+1))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5NCoMwEIXXzSmCq6T-VKGU4s-629IbRDFpokkkxJV4km6k0EP0KL1NExWGeTPzwXvzejO9fAfSdIS1UBKuAJeDNhYGVNrgM1oaX3-P7ZYEkthnAOioGlgjFXWQ9prYyxnvOrG8uhEpCTCtHY2CDKkwwyfEUOf06NbYD3jencnq5XMRhhM4UG0gz6ssSQteVlnqNQwdWInYiCgrXojtfHBvJnfDle0V4pGIat8xdmgGrvagZdn0Dw)

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell (80)

```
f(_,0)=1
f(n,k)=n/k*f(n-1,k-1)
main=getLine>>=putStr.show.f.read.(++")").('(':)
```

But, if input in the format `x y` is allowed instead of in the format `x,y`, it's 74 chars:

```
f[_,0]=1
f[n,k]=n/k*f[n-1,k-1]
main=interact$show.f.map read.take 2.words
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Scala 54

```
val n,k=readInt
((k+1)to n product)/(1 to(n-k)product)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python (52)

```
 f=lambda n,k:k<1or f(n-1,k-1)*n/k;print+f(*input())
```

Improved from the other two by using `print+` to convert the result of `f` from `boolean` to `int` in case `k==0`.

Still have no idea how to shrink it to 39, I wonder whether they are using lambda at all.

Answer (score 0):

*(The OP only loosely specified the input & output method/format, so the following seems acceptable.)*

### Sage Notebook (<s>39 41</s> 40)

In the current cell,

```
f=lambda n,k:k<1or f(n-1,k-1)*n/k;+f(*_)
```

where the input in the form `n,k` is entered & evaluated in the preceding cell. This simulates "command-line input" by assigning it to `_` (similar to command-line arguments).

### Sage Notebook (<s>42 44</s> 43)

Alternatively, using "in-source input" (with only the `x=` and newline characters adding to the score), e.g.,

```
x=5,2
f=lambda n,k:k<1or f(n-1,k-1)*n/k;+f(*x)
```

*Both of these approaches are obviously spin-offs from earlier answers by others.*

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 80 bytes

```
proc C n\ k {proc f n {expr $n?($n)*\[f $n-1]:1}
expr [f $n]/([f $k]*[f $n-$k])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFZIS9GIVuhGsxJU8hTqE6tKChSUMmz11DJ09SKiU4DsnUNY60Ma7nAMmCBWH0NEJ0dqwWRB7I0a//n5CYWQI3jMlUw4qoF0gpAUFBaUqwQ7QxUCNLCVfsfAA)

Comment: Very ungolfy approach, 165 bytes: https://tio.run/##Tc5LCsMgEAbgvaf4Fy7aQikUeoK4E7xA6qKIC2u0YgwUgme3xhrIbIbRbx5JTaWE@FEY4J@wWI1XEYIk4zTWWScIjPobIqi4jO3TSJlBPWkFP0i@S97lu0n7l@wg2S5Zl26T/c1fqZWk77yd6jTKzrlM7hX6jeSBO8k1o0ZY0oxxqH3Y@nL5AQ

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 27 bytes

First my own 35-byte solutions:

```
f=(n,k)=>n-k&&k?f(--n,k)+f(n,k-1):1
```

Or, alternatively,

```
f=(n,k,i=k)=>i?f(n-1,k-1,i-1)*n/k:1
```

The first working recursively, with the simple `(n,k) = (n-1,k) + (n-1,k-1)` rule. The second using that `(n,k) = (n-1,k-1) * n/k`.

**EDIT**

I just noticed the solution by Arnould in a duplicate of this:

```
f=(n,k)=>k?n*f(n-1,k-1)/k:1
```

Which is a whopping 8 bytes less (27 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, 16 chars (8 bytes)

```
Ans(1) nCr Ans(2
```

Input is a list of length 2 in `Ans`.
Output is the result of the formula defined [here](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/ncr).

If the above solution doesn't suffice, then the following **35 chars (24 bytes)** solution also works:

```
Ans(2)!⁻¹(Ans(1)-Ans(2))!⁻¹Ans(1)!
```

---

**Note:** TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does ***not*** equal byte count.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 1 (or 5?) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
c
```

Builtins ftw ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Takes two loose inputs, \$k\$ as first and \$n\$ as second.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@f9/Iy5TAA)

If the `"n,k"` format is mandatory, it would be **5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** instead:

```
',¡`c
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXefQwoTk//9NdYwA)

This will split the (implicit) input on the ","; pop and push both values separated to the stack; and than uses the `a choose b` builtin.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 13 chars

```
=COMBIN(A1,B1
```

`A1` is n, `B1` is r. Surprised this wasn't restricted, honestly.

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 19 bytes

```
l~\_m!@@\_m!@@-m!*/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/P6cuJj5X0cEBQurmKmrp//9vqmAEAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
àV
```

[Try it out here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=4FY&input=NSAy)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 byte

```
c
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWMmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD01JTBBMiZmbGFncz1y)

Built-in.

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
w$w÷$$-w÷
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPXclMjR3JUMzJUI3JTI0JTI0LXclQzMlQjcmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD01JTBBMiZmbGFncz0=)

Non-built-in.